# Transform 7-segment display pattern into number

Tags: code-golf, number, ascii-art, parsing

Given A and B, where A is the scale of a Digital LED Pattern B. Parse pattern B and print the number.

input:

```
1
 _  _  _  _     _     _     _  _  _  _  _     _ 
 _| _| _|| ||_||_   ||_ |_|| |  ||_||_||_   ||_|
|_  _||_ |_|  | _|  ||_|  ||_|  |  |  | _|  ||_|
```

output:

```
2320451640799518
```

input:

```
2
 __  __
   |   | 
 __| __|
|      |
|__  __|
```

output:

```
23
```

**Rules:**

- Use **STDIN/STDOUT** for **input/output**
- I tried to mimic [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/transform-number-into-7-segment-display-pattern) question as much as possible, but I think code-golf suits this one better.
- Shortest code (*in bytes*) wins

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Given a number A and 2*A+1 lines of input…"?

Comment: @reima You are right, the pattern will be 2*A+1 lines. I wanted the style of the question to be as similar to its original as possible, so I changed it so that it doesn't mention the number of lines at all.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 151 characters

```
s,*r=*$<;c=r[s=s.to_i]
i=0;(n=(r[0][i+1]+c[i]+c[i+s,2]+r[-1][i]).tr(" |_","01").to_i 2
$><<(0..9).find{|j|0x3df9778eb5c5b>>5*j&31==n};i+=s+2)while b[i]
```

Leaves out digits it cannot recognise, but some invalid digits are recognised nevertheless.

Assumes the lines are padded with spaces to their full length.