# What size is the digit?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

7-segment digits can be represented in ASCII using `_|` characters.  Here are the size `1` digits:

```
   _  _       _   _   _   _   _   _ 
|  _| _| |_| |_  |_    | |_| |_| | |
| |_  _|   |  _| |_|   | |_|  _| |_|
```

Larger sizes are formed by making each segment proportionately longer.  Here are a couple size 3 digits.

```
 ___    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___ 
|   |  |          |  |          |  |   |  |   |
|   |  |          |  |          |  |   |  |   |
|___|  |___       |  |___    ___|  |   |  |___|
|   |  |   |      |      |      |  |   |      |
|   |  |   |      |      |      |  |   |      |
|___|  |___|      |   ___|   ___|  |___|   ___|
```

### Goal

In this challenge, you are to write a program/function that can take a single digit as input and identify its size.  The catch: if the input is not a valid digit, then your program should output `0`.

This is **code-golf**, fewest bytes wins.

You can write either a program or a function, which can receive the digit either as STDIN or an argument, and print/return the value.

Digits will be provided as a multi-line string, padded with the minimal amount of trailing whitespace needed to make it a perfect rectangle.  The trailing newline is an optional part of input.  There will be no unneeded leading spaces.

When a non-digit is passed, it will still be comprised of `_|` characters, padded to a rectangle, and have no unneeded leading spaces. There will be no blank lines. You won't have to deal with empty input.

Output should be a single non-negative integer, with optional trailing newline.  If the input is not a proper digit of any size, output `0`.  Else, output the size.

Here is a handy guide for the widths and heights of each digit for a given size `N`.

```
Digit  Height  Width (not counting newlines)
1      2N      1
2      2N+1    N+2
3      2N+1    N+1
4      2N      N+2
5      2N+1    N+2
6      2N+1    N+2
7      2N+1    N+1
8      2N+1    N+2
9      2N+1    N+2
0      2N+1    N+2
```

### I/O Examples

In:

```
__ 
  |
__|
  |
__|
```

Out:

```
2
```

In:

```
|
|
|
```

Out:

```
0  //because it is of an invalid height.  Either 1 char too short or tall.
```

In:

```
|    |
|    |
|    |
|____|
     |
     |
     |
     |
```

Out:

```
4
```

In:

```
 ___ 
|    
|___ 
|   |
|___|
```

Out:

```
0 //1 char too wide
```

In:

```
 _ 
|_|
| |
```

Out:

```
0 //it's not a digit
```

In:

```
 __ 
|   
|__ 
   |
 __|
```

Out:

```
2
```

In:

```
 _  _ 
 _| _|
|_  _|
```

Out:

```
0  //both would be valid individually, but input should be a *single* digit
```

In:

```
 _ 
|_|
|_|
```

Out:

```
1
```

In:

```
|
|
```

Out:

```
1
```

In:

```
__|_
 |  
 _ |
  _ 
|__
```

Out:

```
0
```

---

This is approximately the *inverse* of [Transform number into 7-segment display pattern](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/transform-number-into-7-segment-display-pattern), from 3 years back.

Comment: @steveverrill There's not really a such thing as a size `0` digit, is there?  Unless you've thought up a way to draw them.

Comment: This would be incredibly easy if not for the rule that it must be a valid digit...

Comment: @ETHproductions I am aware.

Comment: @ETHproductions if it didn't have that requirement, it would be a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19548/15599

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 250

```
->x{d=y=0
x.size.downto(0){|n|y=n
a=["|
"*2*n]
"XNRDqpm@A".bytes{|z|p=[?|,' ','']
h=s=""
(n*2).times{|i|
i%n<1&&(d=z>>i/n*3&7)&&h=[?_,' '][d/3%2]*n
s=p[d%3]+h+p[d/6]+"
"+s
h=' '*n}
z!=68&&s=' '*(1-d%3/2)+?_*n+" 
"+s
a<<s};puts a
a.index(x)&&break}
y}
```

Given that there are so many possible invalid inputs, the only way to do this was to generate all the correct digits and check to see if the input matches.

I build each digit up from bottom to top, in 2 halves plus the top line. Although there are 12 possibilities (considering that the left segment can be on, off, or in the case of `3`and `7`completely absent) only 7 are actually present and careful choice of encoding enables all info (except the top line) to be encoded into a single character.

the digit `1` doesn't really fit the pattern and is handled separately, being used to initialize the array.

**Ungolfed in test program**

This version uses `.` instead of spaces for diagnostic reasons.

```
#Encoding used for half-digits (radix 3,2,2 most significant digit at right)

#000    |_|  0

#100    ._|  1  . = space

#200    X_|  2  X = no space (for digits 3 and 7)  

#010    |.|  3

#110    ..|  4

#210    X.|  5

#001    |_.  6


f=->x{d=y=0                                        #d and y required to be intialized for scoping reasons
  x.size.downto(0){|n|y=n                          #Assume max possible size of character = length of input and iterate down through all possible sizes n   
    a=["|\n"*2*n]                                  #Make an array containing the digit 1 (different shape to others)
    "XNRDqpm@A".bytes{|z|                          #Each character encodes the pattern for a digit. Iterate through them
      p=['|','.','']                               #Possible components for left and right of digit
      h=s=""                                       #h initialized for scoping reasons. s will contain the digit string 
      (n*2).times{|i|                              #For each row
        i%n<1&&                                    #If i%n==1 we are at the bottom of a half digit
        (d=z>>i/n*3&7)&&                           #so extract info from z and store in d
        h=[?_,'.'][d/3%2]*n                        #h is the horizontal part of the half digit, either _ or spaces 
        s=p[d%3]+h+p[d/6]+"\n"+s                   #Build one row of digit, working upwards: left,middle,right
        h='.'*n                                    #If row i%n!=0 (not bottom row of half digit)the middle section must contain spaces
      }                                            #We now have both halves of the digit, only the top segment missing 
      z!=68&&s='.'*(1-d%3/2)+?_*n+".\n"+s          #If z!=68 (digit 4) add a top to the digit, with appropriate leading and trailing spaces        
      a<<s                                         #Add the completed digit of size n to a
    }
    #puts a                                        #Diagnostic: uncomment to print all the strings checked
    a.index(x)&&break                              #If string x is in a, break
        
  }
y                                                  #and return last value of n 
}


# digit 7, size 2. Trailing newline required. Outputs 2
puts f[
"__.
..|
..|
..|
..|
"]
```