# Make a working digital clock with ascii numbers

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, clock

The challenge is make a digital clock that exhibits ascii numbers in a 24-hour format like:

```
 _   _     _   _ 
|_| |_| . |_| |_|
|_| |_| . |_| |_|
```

or

```
 _   _         _ 
 _|  _| . |_| |_ 
|_   _| .   |  _|
```

and updates the screen every 1 minute (or every 1 second, for praticity reasons). It must reset to 00:00 after 23:59.

Comment: [Very closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/997/8478)

Comment: [Even more closely related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/20289/194): I would vote to close as a dupe if I didn't have superpowers.

Comment: I think, clock with timer aren't the same as any number.

Answer (score 0):

## **Python, <strike>411</strike> 408 chars**

```
import time,os
s=" ";p=".";a=s*3;b=" _ ";c="|_|";d="| |";e="|  ";f="  |";g="|_ ";h=" _|";P=[s,p,p]
z=[[b,d,c],[a,f,f],[b,h,g],[b,h,h],[a,c,f],[b,g,h],[b,g,c],[b,f,f],[b,c,c],[b,c,h]]
A=range(10);B=A[:6];C=A[:3]
while 1:
 for i in C:
  for j in A:
   if i==2&(j==4):break
   for k in B:
    for l in A:
     for m in C:
      print z[i][m]+s+z[j][m]+P[m]+z[k][m]+z[l][m]
     time.sleep(1);os.system('clear')
```

Not so pretty but working.