# Output the full name of titin

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, chemistry

[Titin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titin) is a protein found in muscle tissue. It is a pretty big protein, and its full chemical name is giant as well. Comprising 189819 characters, the full name of titin would take about 3.5 hours to pronounce. Your task is to output this entire name!

## Details

The full name can be found here: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/hyper-neutrino/7d857f89d6d9bb0ab773291116270566) (this file does not include the trailing newline)

The MD5 hash of the output is `ec73f8229f7f8f2e542c316a41cbfff4` (without a trailing newline) or `628c6eb157eb1de675cfc5b91a8149ce` (with a trailing newline).

- You may not access an external resource, be it a file or an internet location.
- You must output only the exact text from the pastebin to STDOUT or STDERR. Nothing else should be output to your chosen output stream; leading and trailing whitespace are acceptable.
- You may not assume there will be any input, but you may assume that there will be no input if needed.
- You may output anything to the other output stream (STDOUT if you chose to output to STDERR and vice versa)
- Standard loopholes apply

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest program in bytes wins!

## EDIT

This is NOT a duplicate of the Rick Astley "Never Gonna Give You Up" challenge. Besides the tags, they're not even similar. In that one, output is a multi-line song with a few sections that repeats the first two words of every line. In this one, output is a fairly compressible string with 189819 letters. [Please don't close-vote this as a dupe of that](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6956/trigger-happy-on-the-duplicate-button-do-we-really-consider-all-song-lyric-ques).

Comment: It also takes 3.5 hours to copy-paste as well :))

Comment: At first glance, I thought we had to output the full name of [Tintin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tintin_(character)), which didn't seem _that_ hard.

Comment: But as usual, we can create a file as long as we count it in the bytecount?

Comment: @Arnauld I would presume that may be a bit too easy :P Dennis was saying too that he kept typing that instead of Titin :P

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, you may. I don't know if you need to count extra bytes for each created file though; I'll need to check Meta for that.

Comment: "the full name of titin would take about 3.5 hours to pronounce" Not only *would*, it's been done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NFR-ADakI-c

Comment: Can you import in-built Python modules, or does this count as an external resource?

Comment: @techydesigner It depends. What module do you plan on importing? Basic utilities are allowed but anything specifically meant to print protein names, if one exists, would be disallowed.

Comment: Decompression modules (such as base65536 (which is not in-built) or zlib (which is in-built))

Comment: @techydesigner I will say that those are allowed.

Comment: I am surprised that nobody has made a Jelly answer with a base-250 number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [We're no strangers to code golf, you know the rules, and so do I](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6043/were-no-strangers-to-code-golf-you-know-the-rules-and-so-do-i)

Comment: @DownChristopher How is the difference not apparent? In that challenge, the output is a multi-line song with a part that repeats the first two words every line for a bit. In this one, the output is a fairly compressible word that has 189819 characters... I don't see how they're even similar except for that they're both KC challenges. Not every KC challenge is automatically a dupe of the Rickroll challenge.

Comment: `ProteinData["TTNIsoformN2A"]`. *Ugh why does Titin have 2 Isoforms*

Comment: @SIGSEGV `ProteinData` is just trying to be annoying >_>

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Now caaaaarefully make the lists... ***Oh crap it crashed***

Comment: @DownChristopher Most [kolmogorov-complexity] problems are similar, as they're all "output this specific string." Since there's a tag for the type, it's most definitely not a dupe since it is a different string (and not by a few chars either).

Comment: @Challenger5 The youtube account no longer exists.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's strange, it was working just a few days ago.

Comment: I thought Mr. Osas have a long name.

Comment: You could probably do this in O(1) time, bruteforcing all the possible 189819 length strings, computing the hash, and comparing. I don't know if the hash is unique, though.

Comment: @Thunda I don't think that's `O(1)`; I think that would be `O(n!)` and that would take a long time. The hash would likely not be unique.

Comment: I'm disappointed that the bash command `look titin` didn't work.  :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Bash + sed + [paq8kx v7](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/paq/tree/master/paq8kx_v7), 11682 bytes

The submission consists of two files: an arbitrarily named Bash script (*23 bytes*) and a paq8kx archive named **a** (*11657 bytes*, plus *1 byte* for the extra file, plus *1 byte* for the specific filename).

#### Bash script

```
paq8kx -d a>t
sed -fd b
```

#### a (base64 encoded)

```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```

#### Verification

```
$ bash titin.sh | md5sum
ec73f8229f7f8f2e542c316a41cbfff4  -
```

#### How it works

The first line of the Bash script – `paq8kx -d a>t` – decompresses the archive **a**, redirecting its output to **t**. The redirection is required as *paq8kx* prints information to STDOUT, which should not be part of the final output. Said information will look as follows.

```
Extracting ./b 26926 -> done
Extracting ./d 307 -> done
Time 15.36 sec, used 1929185730 bytes of memory
```

This creates a sed script **d** with the following content.

```
s/T/methionyl/g
s/S/cysteinyl/g
s/R/histidyl/g
s/Q/tryptophyl/g
s/P/phenylalanyl/g
s/O/glutaminyl/g
s/N/tyrosyl/g
s/M/asparaginyl/g
s/L/arginyl/g
s/K/aspartyl/g
s/J/alanyl/g
s/I/isoleucyl/g
s/H/leucyl/g
s/G/glycyl/g
s/F/prolyl/g
s/E/seryl/g
s/D/threonyl/g
s/C/lysyl/g
s/B/glutamyl/g
s/A/valyl/g
s/..$/ine/g
```

It also creates a large (printable) binary stream that encodes the different parts of titin's name.

```
TDDOJFDPDOFHOEAAAHBG<26886 more uppercase letters>EHGMBPGEKEJDAMIRILEI
```

Finally, the second line – `sed -fd b` – executes the sed script **d** on the file **b**, printing the desired output to STDOUT.

Comment: Watch out, Mathematica is coming!

Answer (score 25):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>16840</s> <s>16825</s> 16814 bytes

*Saved a couple of bytes by:*

- *inserting the last acid prefix in the packed string as suggested by ETHproductions*
- *choosing the next character group in a slightly more efficient way when there's a tie*

---

Assumes Windows-1252 character encoding. Outputs without a trailing newline.

Below is a simplified version without any actual data.

```js
[...Array(256)].map((_,i)=>i<52|i>126&i<161|i==92|i==96?0:s=s.split(String.fromCharCode(i)).join(`...dictionary...`.slice(j,j+=2)),j=0,s=`...packed_data...`)&&[...s].map(c=>'methion|threon|glutamin|alan|prol|phen|leuc|ser|val|glutam|glyc|histid|isoleuc|tryptoph|argin|aspart|lys|asparagin|tyros|cystein'.split`|`[c.charCodeAt()-32]).join`yl`+'ine'
```

And here is the full version:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xb35d1TV1gX6@/srTvfqnFOn6jRVgsoFvSj6qaAoIIoM4dJJY@hDHxwISBsgxEQghPR9KqHSVapL1Rh7/WHfm3NX8Pq94RAkVJ2z99prrTnn2mtvTx26fOjikQsnz7Vnz5w9eux/f9nyvwe3fLQ/DMOtFy4cuublNmz0fw5PHzrneQczJ/0tH53cvCHXcfKjJLcxdXJzsjHpOLlly4c5/evGj@NNF7dcDC@eazvZ7u1uv3DyzPHwlwtnT3964tCFT/F076Tvh6fOnjzj/UdGXZly86403UySt6QZyZ9xJsiH8qdjxPK71POmHfwmb/1Yan4kDfkrE0W2jMuaH8Whm5hSScLYk2aSztipIImlkfYCz/bTqYzpmHFantnS9HK2LCROyousfJyNZcRJJfJQ3mbx2DemL6vp2A7DtJeOPJnIurkw56bwDccw0xnXiVO@Y8tkzkqn7EzGSodpK@fl4oyXSiVu5ER@WpZtjD3OpCLXTqTpZ83EN91MlPfjXOx6UcaRpulZXioOcxnb8/1MRlbw3ZRlRzk/7aRlLeVEpu2EjuWnY9eUVVnMhGkznbNDL5Mz7dh1TTP0Pc92HT8Vun4ceaGdTkVeEpsp1zZTcSb2nAwsGWb8tJ92Yz92bD9lRumUnzE914s933E88/@1/xNebDt55Jh3KnMq2JLDYE5tiTMXt/zHkH5LnppqzXLkvisDnpRl0ZQZtfSJzKel6cicL9WsvJVVy5N5U7qlM60aMv@@rIbSJyVVt6URq0VXjV2SWZlJZFGNyww@t6KmpSYrpi1rsI9qhHjBVRmzZNGSMbkvY9@r@mEPH2m2Y@oralRey4Q0LZmXrvOpS2oa9rJzMqQWpPeSTGJMM54ae/dojGFB7sgcxjAlUxmpmmpe5n03tMxQinEsxU82yQs3g8/XDXkpq19alnQG@PBamJE1WVbV8Lopa@4u6VPzKXlhWdevS0@AX8YCjO/pT/gPV6rwghcyr0qO9Lgydl1NG6FMWTJoejKTliFP1pxfpEv@8mTQlRFZMeSN9EsJhrKkx5Q74Sk1ljsnXRb8eD79pW3LoFTx7yDcc0Vu4yG2LEnNiuSBqtr8gQzgt8jAa8c6YHJb6hbmFuKp/XI7UKMYURctuITvT9H4MvCDPDiDP3fJrBuaspSRyn58xgikEfgYhiy1Yd5NmcNH@cA@vrILdpqHBStxbMUcXZcaMWQJP53y@MmXmKATf2ZFKamGaXmTlor5qwWzV6QrhhHWXz9tZvSg15@ZkWET4WXITIgRYE0bgTxXNU@ex63p6tkd1ZOTN046kLLv5tS8hcmVc/KXLIV6hB4@vWYhkI8HGM0ZqTmhvISnyogZSEH6j8ZpTG/etfCHKTOSUlt4JFC1WJ7BAINOoNakGmN@czLlB/KXL4O74JgjeP99jHMav79W87FUVBUO@NTE8/HkEFZdcX6STouO37TliSNP1CSWdVzq@NySl8baVdIY6xhWVi2pZgDLwAUbvokpzWF8dVWHLddMWC0ts4k0PCnKgouflfMYsPzlwOsa2Zy8iX7D37xWq3T5Cn5xr8mLlJGRNwfg3wtqTK1tvOnLuClVVcrnUnLbwsvvqCWMvx/Lvg0L2o/1u4Xf624YycBVeeJKSe5YMu5cseVpDn9TkWUZsG5IPS2LWPxm@kMvnT4sy8HBXxQGOEdP/SvEHKu5PZYpC/kbcLmr@OKD6JC8UlMytieQBVWix6awVvJAHiIGVNWSLiP1mwnHOeDB8RAIC6Y8RcY4CHM9xBjxr2WnpCeODVtGTbx8zMxJPcKHm1w5vONOuA8fLLZnuKJ4uH7BqtyJDQQAgllG4PxuepMMSyHBp8ppIw1DNoNjhgtDSme8K4uhr8IGBYwy/M2I8NT7zEyDMoyFGEghfRSuyasDMphIIZ2okY3yPIVhIIieptJc@d8dU8oOfJwBPu3swH8hDxjX5cX//VeNhRieqQrwuXKIZyx/q5qwblW9zWNkanHLJuS/gZ8NGTKlmeUkVy0rI5ORvAoQeBlMddW03JTchdlnHLnnwrBYHTWfhDIeIvvNI0@VBAm1HljwSIMrG9OJJvnlRbz/YzjeTPrw4UhNZfkX9/iwQFWcGFFelN5YFpBhZuFU3VK11IKdlVdInCN78IJI@sNjyKN1/NNEeA3JUHhD7iKwetsRvLts/KTs7JbhXBqhm5U751O5SJZi5M1l5O@3yKklF0sxG@Lrjz5RS1sEWXFezZqGJ/XsbqzDspRthXEOGxm1gk/9tVEmcufsS6FauCaVLUAHVZHeKIA/zeyTmiqoakrqvmtxncYA3PeRu32Y1/jkR1tKWGzzKEcgy1FGNYEFjowRoRYYbW@3kBo4FuY@mc2dUONwNoTzLWDVWE5WN@dkIqNqeVXNyRNgRQ2f/kOGzkkRq1GTshq1EIPy1vVkOMTcYYchLNreDnku9xHaALWaPMO//YjtJeIUJr4SSiXYhvW7IyO@DLsxJnkLGecOMtdDWypYOuTgnTLqu/IQ/jyMvDvqq@kAC73E2Nx2JiUrPl5RUXW4iSxvx7JNO67hy9M4o5ZCNepapgcIXYw@4UzgH3MRrFOGp3@HQRRDuRdmctlcVoaixFPllLwMP2fGkMGMAZuOJJlDprwODmiM7INpK0iGXXI/YupdQigahHdVNo/j/TWp6RAy/L3@eVUJkVTv7dyLvwD6ljIw3D1ZiS7l4el1VUjw8X7p28dscpte9BmfWgRFcC/BwuU8YFiGEvzkeTYXJJE2RoLJvpKKe1aNWQlMUPtclo7KwiW8A6gcI3sfk1kDrvMsg/x8Py3TR2NM63wGoy/jhVUpu1I/l/0Y/tWlGoibcG9GXm633MAAwyhGV2UpkvHkkloDF0FMT6sSaELVu0TYqTgyG8mk1wqO21I@hgfOfe5i2nCZAuJz@YtQNfDmGj5ghbBmEgJiBlVBHqnJlJrCs@pmkk8AGgjGQkZ60jIMwMm3mZjPAPJxXaYDN61WVTMLoiOjBOBlZPYKSYg8z8C@JdVMDENG8VRao5k7lBgIgudS8mQcDGAeXygdBadYcbFUt7k8nlp01AICOgsvWo0D6ZRSkiDMR1xZDeB1SCS2zMQyEWVg/FcKk5xxNwCMZplCagRGpogSwQn04ja8oC6lwMEqgsFlpfAdcnLZVSuqwgFg/plLOtPm1Yiq@e7BtLxNqTFYdFBe7IYRpMZEvYwJNmwpJzLzAyZflWoAN5mDQRE9iL86J38vDjC@qr9z7w1D7icyj2UDntiw1zjXoC/F3GbuBj5NfZxoFzIx3EFOnA9sJjLnGkhx32HMRUNGYvU2AyCT57vh0HeNr6Xbh8ev0JZePp0cxThmOFUHMVBxDSz6B4wz4E4Fg2wg7T1MI1dNrj@yIN3bPzTC/UhpgXtCehK4/Hkb4MbnyXisWeYMgUJeBBjeW9i/EEkBySeWW7bRGmdHhKc3slhXotp9qUShFMB5llRlb4jwq0t3aCCC8LxXsPV4OgFNXZ@7GosQ3ICcAj5OkgDnY1BhtJP@F6r2SQvZih@AGQBgQyR5ZNmzm0Oiwrxvhpa2qB5umBA9GhjuJJP4moVwxXgcaaiGq@aQK5t525D5n5kr58E9lnxYcdpMq7fHpMnE3QX/mU5J8QCSCknoK0yvL4lAXGc09sP3sUQe6DBmajgHZQ0Rg9i6j6VvyIgad/gSawuWoTeCA1azl2Q0juEKLtHi7VUL83rym5TfcfqC9OrBq8UEnjmO73WrRbymjAm4qhj4AAKMqmj44KR4wmvyhWks@B01HLj4/b5MI1@uALsxE//6QWf/JhCPJTz2UUaaxMtqgvWcN84jLPDNhrxMY0GWYzUKR5Xmd7BRyXHBuiel@a2sfhEQmVNqLQY0FBhQeQOkIQIYTmU2YsyzGYVgWwBjHW1rc2GjPlfKN9LyKC9rcNiULKXg@D15BdnUiQha4ppfIcNo8IVLe6xUXpUO4qd3g8NQSRgphjmpZgFDoHvD8vsx@cNI4c3deVsrnCby3xOktycOAgb@OATbgOA41k@w8CObUT6BOXdR4zCTP8nIrA3KVZE7CUB7Wh4GGfByIPE0OEtnCnkGXgFJVLa2I1aG8Mg3GHj@A1ncjMVzMAXnegLL3kfuxTem3peltEL0DfngNBamPC1PtsG6jmuDgBUtWIR8BSnWVFyboXSScyy4YlHWjMDNgS8go8Ft4FpLCO@qPEnkDfy8IfdjJPN5194n06REKzBr3ZX71yMPfmoxXDGcORkJ3HxbGgqiKEUXCZFpZ5y8BrEDovCcfKTpXJbyNvg8XgKufw9J2ZC1oxl841fnBynEHnED8QZHkSW8bPoaZmSFJ8CTRjNbbLkPj7dlxHKwCE0ZQb5FRorJk25S7DhhkDHyBhh4w@WiN4D2DfCuYqRqjmXAbWeB3sORncK63QXsq1VgJ8zxCGBupe0NKenyDbXwPoRvTGtVYE7MVlVSFNR3QL2R72DxUGrgLKSGjfgcgu42uGUhtsA46VngG0s@bIv03yt36NRIx12wnBrW1NIxNv90BOEIjXBeTQWAnNI3xHtwI7WU3IAx720jVb1/9Gt5BZjbLpNtEXjmgppQZfuEWoCjA0Co6UF2wIieelLYKUXY/IdUOkhBJq8psCZXniawftPKqrfQRW8yYPr34o0AJiAeeX2ZGtCSgSjPKDqGpL6Sg7tXt7YytMylZQFcciyGzwyFstzBeQ2AKYCIgb0NyZ0OmgkfKZOoLdssQaxRsoMqMg8hon7dmQFj24@/QYqxEdedZHD4xLIPw9dMZNU1B58dcn7aBVGGl@INWoL24Y9LPkjyciyPIAkodaec63DZlbOxDDuyyOEhvxXkqVr7DRGF786S6iD/35USRAlz7qLLEM8D4xzpBvEzyU/cBOrtOqBPmruQVEfDG4HcjcBjpimm8phfChDASOiWviOcTSctyfGW6VSwOzIp0vi0Kp@AEgZjy@4E9kOGIXOpsQxt91ING1id0gcR0tuTiALxFSZYT5hKy3l5nRfwnjpYYZRNUdf2HA3wWyy9SNlNOx/tktGfIIa4fH@BgdcheUHVpmBJ8IwkwOtnQQKAF0MgFis5UloQujDn0DWYn94ApaZh6@LnXPslVwY3wbCQaw9UXY3/gq8vgPlC5wJECnBQfBmTLO3mak5Yh1TzN/sETYbxlD7DsycotWHkz7GcZy15Abt68JQ3iKyXF7FKEWnH6@2byHdW4zhAMniZqAVrkyqcw9xXMMDnG6Cdpfk9vBBrBcFWPmp@RpkwQ4wpg6BtA7MdwJwx1b7dqhSaSK/zMgKnhxwoE2QaYFLMPQU1/xkyRbeal1mKjQdODtSptjtiuaMOOo@kMEv4BxEi7YEdoVmxNtdVBXCOMUJQZGjEGCs0u50RlkcwABinYsypQVIBrOWapgAv9W@pnaGnqAQ6or3ahERUAK8TKYRTcX3awMXkw1T6KtagigCE1EI@4q@zn0nnPqp9B66G5cezMMy@FkuRNw487i2YDxJHl1TOR6ECVhVkdX/gQroVXNvGJwvSlwOvkZXtlGfP90kx3bImVd7s50wlWOoWi5wOIjJRzj05Gu6WfqhmA4mK1nRZzIBppiFCn7isPtVtI22wOKZTC6TyLA36nNrhVbpl0ZeQXGWZp8GevjMpWbQbgx5IwaRQuGXsk9kzGNG9DAjDq5ZJN@A5E0jFcMpCSsac3dAKnuG3mXSjNjjlF5vVonZJAOP9n7Q5kW6eb3ZTqhkkW@CQZjoNldcyZ01ef4Iw0NUmoMEwZy4N6KmZTfQieRghXupZhgiySRmsFugyF2Juz/eaWDAIA0jL6BBivmTDCE0YRC2mmD5gN8UcBs@U@o9wTIiR1vIkMIw2pfQiCGddZL6HCr62GsrYDXkZRFuJ@zAC5qwfuiGfnEA@A@2gkscgSxHrqQAIg9PWI/37qayt0hWfqwoCaT4GCxhjBO1B8prAqq9cwufHaK9S2tALhFSEZY6TFAxSBIk3gSqFI3qsy2k87CWo6Xl6fNGEOHoIsPPx@y0@1Eo@wfShxnIwbae8DvXK1fb6l4X1AMgcaCYsQZk5Fj/xNuJncKumQ0Vy6ws4atmFDo3kpa3XXCHX1iKW7SJDenOAdg8TeGHbn3CoQOlhJEcm6CfhZxa8e4BQWga0pTH9vqzAqHfUyCaNTXdhpNEjyBjD0gNxPXFULebAyCGrkLEXIIsYSxC3cicSYGpdS8eiaWyDqmlIM3tMJkEaGgjOZbjlgi9zm0C8q@2qBqkXwHaAiDxr5po//o5PjluRqnokcwzip20k/oH2gIYvzS/k9vsfcqmYFWrZ9u8IpktcqFgtxYCTzeE@PHILl0mVczaeXUfsVkOd6wAf9EXoURD@iCZ9mkb4DJCKrpwA@4a/NchlEgOqq3E@DiwoUDjq5hAEL49vLIfQ4e3EKkgW8Pc@KV8G7Md0tQes@w5EHtRDCTliLhfZOYdLtqLJrFpBpoFiQ4z3y4qFhPGWI@iLz8dqTE1iTe7vCRCaSP7ND7A6LyMs0iMZw@LrWmlTVn2pXs7KHTjvv7Ayf1HcwMlDmcoiM89ASa24oBtr34MqpjFx0K@3WKsXSehJ7xVox@gw86hLX5mTx1wX/NckkIY12tKpr3KnZeUbhdyAoNwgPVl5Yl9lfTfS1d9G5LGK0XWJNRZW4DLn1Jxrk3w1iZ8PHHzxmYuohXiX10dBaF4jqGdP4SezH6ni/0gxzMudtIwmWZD@xLhBllJSk9@DtaQTcLt2DOOPGAypqmahkIqYfkkeRAfgV6aBQdg6NMtIfXOHISMhgcEK/nLkGZJNNg85isxSNs@DFBqIimkokJUj1NEjIZLONXjxLMhwSO4wD4RZxThfygsIGtAbZu3zUnlvL@wga198hBfTvr@yyDkF5/V0nbQRIQGtyVyUUo20LOVS6q2Xlxd78vLoip1TtQ6ZNKTbgbHmoq8QHdkwAmouQj8AErKRIEPInxC8/yP1MI@Eubg9@0P@Crx9v@F/z0ru82zObscAT4QWawjLLud2B/r4NhJKFwgbnzQBzjMNK5WQOMf3w@idXB0118HiPDjaAwMp0YpADCtSTMDWYpipkVE1V265eE4vAq1408vrnSEWpSYvIMk@tg9Am3@uVlxkuVI2kbUw@he9oX4WviUjXhaoD4ynakqwEDM3VJ3M7Hd5@wNUWC5tX8FqD4KrS99vm7Dmj81Qp3v8YNSGr5WyquzAshX5K4v5y4QjT7ZnZSy/x3CYsPox8bSU9sSqEspbePQfKRl34GIYfgcWu6BYpF3LgmiCz9YiL71Bxk4oEtjgNCIRameChY9ZE7ytkGXZc4Xl@n4LTLwTFPDHdd@9eUYWjh@Xe45q5uXNjZyswWnDLB0rkUr8NSkIHju37aNv/i23Ihnbmc5aJsuanHu8VRoOSe1iCu/j3EFrxzHNV74UoUqbunTflH5HHufsyzLwudwK8GXGQZyclmdqNORAY7DVlPTivVhFuOu4E@UTDI9hVgSswZhN7ln94cu4lw6c420ZmL8II5T0gGViN/1xfGeQUSP2L1/F3wnEHtICIM7IOwj5bVkjlEm4EHn4LJas7p@DYyIVTSCfj91UoHLVDuS3eT9hoXMUI5BlE0YumwGYu96GwZojZ87JW/JN2L1KN1jl/psMIuOUPk6iQOYBYTKHnD8G241nWLxEpN2AhJmRwQ/w0ZcQ@JT9o@BQg3CzWF4fY8ZhVpNeBywNYyqHoCTjZ7m/4IH8LOzBq5ex0Ck62gK3Zt5K7WbsIbfhT0WZPQzGMa9mY0vWEFuwcX3vYVNWkLQqv8haKvevjIGkE0PRA3pg6Ft5tQJfmKPWfCV9aSn/KEuf0sZfynwHxOSMrO0HkNPPkNNfAilLLKiGaVXYhbAbRN5YdHKOKZUs3LGQMBMB@gtyi3sjMgY5tMCtHaRogHCnlCDcQerUDEJwAcQOVlcLYB9RoIZzBr5Xh/WuUWBtleqFn@TxB@TeS5H0bFDNY0ycE/KnL3cTDBfKbhRusoxQzAIsGojE4SBP/ty4QeK5pNM95qL3GuRxntzjCFcVf34cydNIloHQn7tqxkiR5gCPRhPMB6GFgCz/inTYHVyEx6iqmk64JbLoyWoK7BNJGp6OTPfHl448fx/Dugd@/AmS9DzjXNVZnngCod2PVSlj2Ae@wxJhkH9JU9Vi64j07rkY5ttiTnnMklefZbg5yjrSsFRv2ofkMei85VDOYVRdskbVMIEJ1EA0RzOGDhDuTt2Wxs8yt9/j3oAPxjABxQioXk081qpHiP02njkaAFIn4IQzaiYvizHUEvek699qTL2QkmVPGslOI4@JZhG64IowcyXN8lIxhJ37jMDMhhhRsW1HnGfNcph26MKI32LR@/YAM/MYNbjEI9gPLpOCHUoU53AtP8S6d@P1E1lZcnYwMNUoPFFuhYir5UgtwcpyK5V3pN8l@YB/T/ggGyfh3@CzC8dd6QRdVaORKniyRm0@jOAfS5NWSs2@she2ePC9dBogGMWLsVoxGazLJmZ/H@@FbYBbIzYkKsP3DIjudl09RIJOkHWwsG@TvVI/GGnADpPLTCUgtm4@p4HqqUxg1DBJkCMRQRIc3BmTyEByf83FuZW7liUAqPGTzCQVVooLxwCzHLWabYfzP1ZzMbL4i/2yCIerYsnW9FOdFgKUf/UZTHA4DPUpUoKXlllqGxayQ@12tU9tQ40kX2bk8XGukifjapYICKdz8zJE1JiKuQuYSiPgpe8jDa2GdP0o/RHiXSY7ohuUzWXI47mEJbVhjS608yE@sx9@Wge@ZaTLl6Fv1Womreaj/JH8GfZc9GiXK/z8E15yirkqlr4zH8vqXnx@KILaLZvyB97/Enl3KA90DUx5fokIuAdEFsRhcQuYkaHpFrxqVqpwJcD@Fpn@xXC@kFVwlQKJBlzDzMjqGcL3JNPwIkaGFDLHCpxvWa3k1wrua/Q7EyiCj7yAPXI6@@E5sxl4KfBrL55OrPlIGsG/85eziogIuLHh0YAYLGbdh3iEusLTwegW6HZfMl24MuMhTUcfyjNohzVXrdJkTcPnN3oTIUvt0xUgUHaTiA5YWIvh0mACDrcbnwQyeQMsWJ5sTclLx3LPgnFgWECEm7B/L3LokhGeUM2f5bHHapKClKmCO1@V6axe2VFNOoq/clN0KrtXqsdlaau8UvUbcInAZybKGKCfqnLtii7mDkGIJan3WehhjgNEISWGauaqTNJfh3IfcdMzy4rFKOPtlnaMENmrYF9NAQIR1A0MsSiL0acH6W8c2CA8@B6ZHEy8iw6HGceIEq7Qa6Bc@SJp7b@kAYfLyRKAxD8Vp7UsGJPeG55@5FL6gM4Y1ZsZwOIVJCyN7hgIt3ocSlCiylgUZmQgkPG0vAzlLnhrFUJgzWEdPDHUCiRhJ7LiDIbYz32n1yxBJB/uCKxzl8AE@9TKoZ1IkHdV7QLzG3Ihcv7lIEHeXnGBs9n34a0ftcwq987aahmpltkghLScURgpGOZzWzvZLvnDzUDVPtK7TcghWEaWQyog6yETZfkzaYAjNVocERpRAxTh24X26t0mTRCERhJhtad34iU1bQckroeg9zfVlBoHpZPmVlDOCggBZO6auRtmeMsCe48nCwdsjHvsEmQUTF2lU4z68gDM/ouw1ciCVblMOCxIX8iWgOe5PDQccmi3LO5EDv8QyXUgCpyWh1WBQQUMdzQHq80zTUz86xsy4Fg3p4x6WdDPhiuDtt5XrdLNsIygtZvBQHNMbLNMXwvGGYLNWzKop0edDPVo4z2YB2sky4Gsqjk@tvyraWgfe8F3OpsdeRXrLzGjfXiSCsfPXEurWZcsbvlbAvQuRh5l05BNdZhXM@AypSxoTRj8i8Kp/lvsnZc72bNqERlmiLnPhOT9nuVHMNNJ0mXC6D3nE5nrQNKtgZqVv9oHGbxo2PLGgt08rgFQRI28C2As0y@yFIWYz364@Sp4rUewLEtPYn/iy@q1S9yrOGwjG3EnoqaaWijgC2Wp@tLznkYLRD5pitfSCvDvQTWfvU7J6Max4s6k9AUptZJOLFIUEGYrB@mhHewnPK9gQwrs1iE2uhtMGXMHbFWP0KxRqPVCijGGBN1rIasXWCKChwmSOqQuhNJUOzM6iPiUGgbRhJRA3i7mpQthCCOTStRSoM7DnubabEVqOrBDT7rFafuy@NkqUknBVIUAPgupzG3p16ypFpK8DIfsh/gNQ6kmtjaHJ7cDKTHcHpvy6IMMXtGQoeCqzHPZZPQjaIl/g5g@AZsws@eYkxZdgtWsqgfU5xDqE62UHmfOYeoT0I0A8b4gfl/TezXnEZMrPpjYjEbPTlXVxsgZPolyA2IRX5@UKfgiFAulA0LtYfrrk99q6YQVWL4OCc48l6cIoIkzhzGECEz9jSkPjlA8yfRHZIAQux/iD71YuyT8ACGXkh4rb9N1mRvTaoVGLthqERiwcEXepLjx/hLuC/L@lbZxYwsWvwLdpcZNQGcRIVDDQg855E/LukzTZMntlqqlQG2kM8TX7mcATNQNrH38juTWl8jrdABsZe8ZlOkzefRhgulhwRuylGyV@VOHW@zkG9K1erssJ1acvohhDUJqpQApi2oa/67kci3SGnvn5JEpRROmUkU1chiu/gy5eCjZDcvF3MRpHpTZbAjUy32UyHQuoOidlcUvToV7Y1nEEM0gZ6hamEeasTInVWM//BmPuJdlNeGODHzGXL58AV@aPtcS5vCYHsTJOCg/gk2GflBsAxilli6F10NuRcE5HshrLHgJvGIHPPC5ohvNfE0Xa/6Qw8Jraa6rQEB3dnbcC7d6@Wz0VXSaO0sJM06sQENuGV5Wui8RwEsO2@0agBguGzNZy82Avo/bkHO4alMsAi3/HH3FZsgqwOuqDGSTr3IcBMvRYO5MsUtxIN1QTnNaFQBrz36sGsjsnVHgf8qQQy67ArJKkakVJPcxERIUsiAB/TFr26l0Vs0dPA2S1ypaGfIspssOOqqQpipDTLGfdAzKdI2peAJ6tOuklwfKW961n2UFLAQvX2Z9u/wVVg@gaYQ3AExjMg4S3ZNCjh@RsZ@p2hrZnV5aK4KxGFhTOyJPjAPkIsCHMIL8AkErpcCyDrG5pYkAGoPyekRqBn72@YZ8ANCxv0rkT4v86Vd5QB7CCgoJ5wY2qdECc@mWg0njpp@TR8gkJmneMlx8ECE33QFOthPrP@NfjdUMECubgmWGT0sfeB4dPYcYvgOF8SBUy/4lXbKdPtJiDbqeyUz5IpHbrM114rMr59gutWQB8NdivcXMHsiCjENbIkA/OajmAsc89guUJkVDQ15D6t4OuD/w2lXFjBQ@D9@Tv5jSSVl75YlFCB0gPX0qj5G1Nsl8BOM@sDeCiwVIoWX5M/nm39Q/1fB8VhoAu0FpbNjiyXNocsihd76lS4jzHVK6HhseQpetoLDI8TghDILSymgevP0HKItnauEj@kGKQmsJNE2B99XUojyhA3T7OScv45qWli@B6eXsE2eYOYmVbTnM6oXhIA6QHn15@TkLW9V9wFonDnRJlJhiH5PO8zELS1/L08DCPIAcr9h6XN6m5j@Fo7wwb1K5sgQEgxflD8BEiJlP/2Cwu06Hr5kgdUzIzLdqzgARq8Kuq6bew0PgFwzbsMIktVXKIJ6T4XvndcmDdl1UbKsBGddQCXvVMnuMHMLWNmSaih5GReb6XdV@hV58lmRhLn5jTiruRqlTyiO0MkhbqnIONMFTax0Yct/hHEscY1iLNdCYhEU1oE2VfObBOkaCelg3tYIIKfWLoI2zoHfDWKde/yRmyp5GB9nongyeAdsDs4WwgNZeO@DEB9nriPFXsfZqzs6tL1JdakxS9xLaM5FOi80OUyEbhNQwdMET69ODNxHNf9GW92Rue5BzCAmZr2Qh4HbrsEztwy/j0jDYATqnIWEN3KNyEYkbnjEM8puGpQvSzRLrE27PqDK1BjLUOA83lKRMGf8cgcH22lqrUNL4TObfwywaNOpdDDfJsdsJ6mYlVFUdsG0bNxC/El1ZdTW9BTT6OdIvWTDDiD1fgxajf4DRz@Z1sPuNGajJZWSuP0PtUwMcV0nu7MlaoQcPAbDev8RdpdKPHJIusv@BlLVA3j2CtRiQF1/gF6iRCUraziiVz11GCpthWgQBAETNyVNXO9UC2eUMoaAKY7@@Kf0pNZWLPozfNUFVZBa5DIjKRp15RqxC7gE1f0QmpKktK16zWZu8o@VccLJbyHSTexC0ebZFQIuazFXh7h8N/92Q4WCyANF9HEZ9ETibQFL5jLWESDMWKG6ZltSymo1lKr2u2wM8uvl33N5C3E4h/xpIrG@/pz3KJz1KdtAPjzS/8zhhYcJh4VaHLBwX35XGPrXcoSqnkZ5K/8NyAtiAi1X7GAQXPjHn521CQUufPj8JJO37WsapfZ7Cwt2@KXepHeQhD2JM4QUskaySrRF4M6oJ1jQPrJ@TTizoRe4pjEqPLkYza4JqQUTx4zl23Y8e0naeOYypQSiDoNWkobkdjFxntFVlhQ1uJV3EKH8kBVdTfVViz9qyBzYcqVF3S@CxLD76DnWrN4OcPL@iGselRvbAQpw89tlxUU20ipphBLNjluUnXboNubdVlWHEmy2FnwhLw8c0LHTJoqn1Q8gS62PYYZDlZohJG2HAksjhgJSxn98fhOyfC3KnsVwVDbqBFQMWC3aWxeB@6WWZDLbQNQa5b7IBj945j8VD2HlXbCBmxPpWXd4YcGVE/ISsgAmbR4i6iIEeVmLmpPAzG@gaZDfJB/DVkFugSZur1pAtWRZJQnYTP8errkrxMJyaXfR/4y6WSoYdYGflPWnsBkB07kPcfQPcnQnZh9wtM/vzQbyV20TTP6qyjmLP0GF8pU36O6RmwxRPSZkXTmQMXVzu5kaZA/0IVNDTL6r5nbJ4VEGnVUxuM7AgBFJV8rkp@YoNg8ZNV8Z3wL/ekMy8/MwyjRQmNiHD134j1eiTcYiCAk8rsHqxDHH@S3ze4laLabFqugSzzki3KiJ@VvIwEqTpoxx7El4k5MzeebBjNbqX@@GP/xu@oHTcWXofnC45DXvOU0vXjRC6bkH6s1JHejBZF@iHzoOzlkyMHtyLO3C5c2QeFdfOQvos5hz1Vjttr2Ox37TxHuVI0LHO8LVzLYXfqWLWAqCdIYfBUN@CbmOMq7tOYpJ/GDKudCFo@bhx@e/AlbkTiFtIz4bOM/DfV@k0vllx9QZJZ6LGsqwXv5@AoKkVniTBM/3ItvnQvuRLex1vbals@QIuxR1TeH2N4h6Tk9lDVBpl4EVVw4Np@Bdb2wxlZL0@/FogY2xKN1IL2IR0n1ULaRsrV0LYptNaY2ZYOqxRMSDGHl3WAl1GYqz0emlpAuxLrQYA3wZD97JaTn6QEdUgRZllGX12PXLhDEiOV6R8HLraybF8zq07uLkJPzVkIJ9NBw7WR9c@/n12u4xbYMmF/B5oiRIilqdDYIEfA/9kxtDbC/L0Ok9ENdUkxNiTb0kO0ofDCxgG65e7KHYzufU0YEh9F3zPV4Us/KuBkY8TyV1mKdo10YXoHpAjI8H4h6/YbPzr5WZzFBqpr3SDEKA3Jg3ssfNbZTi1HqsRSSwIUxTwhM1EDHAoujyH9QqJbCqd6O1gkmSNu/WkxWgOrEfrYyti40xjgy7/kJBM/wsCGcHaHZ5BrCL9Jflgwy@qZqWkK72RBJkbeYRckNgVk5pRx@szsuHn0AbG58SDKrnRsh8g9HW9w7D2c3NUAPszTMY@fqvoMtWCzz28qppXK7GuzYRs25zTSpSlqjVbvUXiaX6N/NM8xH2vGosdmZ9/QkBkA255zCFkSXYmkc@6/UTNpHQfAtblTeSluRNVQ6afgUsWzRPyUhM5xityONH2AfURPOoxa1/uBwlCgKeI@k0uVpUC7AUyQcHeIrMmZP6nu5CxAQPSnTtx3AQ7/keYcn2m3VAtGL5q6B2ZeZKOlxpn1@lxEfT4BJVrHTZpAsf1tlVdI4Gauqb3R6t@HqMGn8trksi217u6Bsq2UXAZM4c8@D9sxl/Sx0ayHwM71hJ86EnQonJSj4KQwfoi@fLb48RYRFcFj2SYroUyb6hZzHfUZKHykAsb1@RBJqfmFEvRcP3zwKfprzH18jsmB3@dhqph70zNTVOpziIVeId26N7yv@OU5@t4RGkl3nqZbPa@/BkxqACECA6WKAYiqHlE3vQxxmiZMfqKReB3MYon9B1eR7KnZ1pR2njPwEhP4R2DCKpWgaPMXLWUlh61HELl3doHxjaMf3TxNwkibdIvId0oN@zfzuR1cR2LnxyOuQtSQah@K9MXGalafdOieX1UYkEtG1tlzbyWyBR781msjgM/B0jN5DXvxmcCxCRbOu5KfRt7TyKtZMuIU@7w9SDIF/8bqGYrUJ97bPvoQSaVu5/La7Xmpi4wSHM6Rpn@yozRXsZogzHaKiTOMmSAqFWpnPpHlGpIZbN6A2EKWfqLWv1voPKwTytQ1bzJbo4CTxTOWa1AVbV3gdracYfcsv5tWEi7SLFZGcmz2uNi9W5/IyULYaq3IwduboM73nN2XJY59meNHpEiaEXNOSCvL6mGp8Yj3QoM2NOQqvsXVpEqdISC5Cvu8ZVMnq1ZMhG9sqrGc4A8DyyDByOmmMCYIye4M7rGBtUa24SqzDQM00TWUkSrD6m5GvSAfun3spH331Cd1fnfhEj6lJQG0arGXTZYltkjMMWIzbHI@VjX1WUGYAYMeGkRWif1htb/DVgtwViPDyCPECngj4jY4smDDNhzMOYgsGTkHxELiBviKYxaCNeuyH1a@KD8aeiY1QArq@F6zILLmNY7gD0a/gNfl0EkujH/ik1mXGd5jVHL6vMT8I/JQ2YLYveSFZuCvDJ8nmcJfRfjQNR@DQ5vs@2KMQtyB0sjZodlECBJVQtR/4@wVY3vNbpulNLFd1E7z9xZX4dWEv8RboPMtLCVcdvavFmPW1eequbHh1s75Y/xgjLcctd7V708Fu3ZOri2DLAjzW6kAjevQvYsIWq/J78AvOqY9a5cl5mDhFY1q6HVTD6hiOln6aVCKqyxdb3OmTmGQLzja2x1LOTTYebKJfZSlgBBGlu9vH0i9pAYFpjHAK5wq6Ht@qwFXI3bTsNxmmc9ddS@2AxS@JbnGClr34BUqrXt8LYiIGpSXllsAkjyUZisK9rZVtQutqJWC1orufyZjL134IiWs@xnqSXce21BK7y96sYbN7CJA6z1RzWii5ukwdI8xzI20jCAtcYT0ro75DkhOuKJxpIMpoy/0bXZKsHxWEvvNhZNV9zYg2Fvg167aekCs7RzwFY84J6Dj6fXsRWIOOq4GHknsPWSGiW0glbX5eXP8iwBz4SBVjv@Rta6b2oy3AQrW0LyHyUiPNc70DNYE8jZGZ/nw14yLS@3dmrG1vkweR5A4RRLE4xcUOJ/rweumQ2Mf2Asuf7/CVwWL5/KhHtGXqpGjtH637htuAiSUctIAWoZuew8iVsNM2VLluJ/Yu2oPInXwXYColYeqrf/P7yl2/4TcGHJSpiwRj0LwLX/BtzR/xu85TbGLvH26Du4TaTJnejXfwPuKo8LDJJ8A3DxGQCuydeRHvcQcSMZeMeOfdOWF0igwFwMegrirBbleYq@Fb2zMp14acIDVqrSit5FeOkjmf1eY24@d5kpUu6fhovNB9wXY/wyy1tSbVMN@wS3R2/wCoP/UuNrOnwfQWTkD@OvuXXTjadWbbJjj6d3XrBKBwP7Ajr3DnjHkBn/psg6hH8M3JM/6AA@7n7bbucjO7UuZWO2lLi6InW5hbhsc9bO@xnA8IGflX4ibhqp5zkTIsa4lLS9Q1wkWOSYGRh/kYmoK5Tif2kx72xAXsNfa7htQIuM8Wyv1E6BQl/D8EI1j083CLhQgS8h/BqaF6uxXKIxFz68KFMtXnydPjfJs59vpPYeKR1cdx9CmCq2n8R45ptka6sCU0z@SYx5zqPFjLWQ5aYa0IoO1UjBfo2QFYICY9ddF7ItZrwtK91brdYhiBnSp9IhvTH@wzrchlZKxy14PtFxmXtgiFsIOCokbgjqA89zyFkWNxl4ZMIyudevg7cKq08xXoi63LEHWvbKw1QenjvDvYkKy5VyV2MB3KBHsTU1j5RdQSJIvsqd1jEb83kgxlnkgCrPQr1ALoKOGyOgL/qfcm9GM@PXOeTT1zaCfiXnvK/diWJmIOBZzW6DW6wWtyD@y41zvPTgtWLry2KsirsAtDQfotVXw4Y8bAfWcstdnm@E65cdfPtdsI6TIOoyVBUTnYVvsUzSp8OV@2o6XGUWKfEV1GyXmSNB9ltg@y3i1aYA0G1z3ZrL1ahn10LPMNjI/jZiSqsd8mT2AxBkoMMz6fSYHvt4NBFoG8qLtozMm1ESmLrWzHgNAdHjWMHSerFvh3fzWKuAPO5IOfMdD0fFLMv/LF2n5YFazeWCnQjUAECbAXgvyH1DlY79U8N@zwqqxtkfWlusbFxllYQtbewakyX3aip/MZQhl1A7z/5cFp9mdPFJJmOQEMZpDVpAhn/EW7RZQZBhoxGI2RQ46woBt7NVn4/ZYpqmn1d2IZHi75sMWkjWV1JXk6xoPomyG3geapiZ4ZX2XESw5gVkj5NsAuL2yT3uW1q74EBv5I6T2gRnHeEtIvv0zhpS6VW2JP4sc4lqYgV5qGfYDNmCK/1qIcQcSwg1tRgm73iyGoVhp3mVSOlIC3HNhEdRP9dHNGDZSOb8RCeZJBewUWIwPpOFhzSSJJ8wIU7qfZ@udAt78TcLPLB/jkckIWyR3mo8prbsfnUjrbGG7LuUTb0D3ilNjmxu143HCeyT54FI6Q4Cj447DDgceVeitlhggxneQMl2Kh7NtPTG18cJTxIG5kEWBxcTilu8fb5V5kTeCeFj7Oyfga2aSZvekih9kOIUG@zMDOUh6CEy/eu09J@R5gfQSMiJz1r6Fpgb8SQkP8xuVepbi7HyewrPfMOLbG4r1i41/prGx97HjOQF/1PAz/oeUBSoVRdKGqxGOnO6CVa6nWxr9/YNKLmXJvhWQZsZ74xldsNo7LUQzDd0pSsA3DbYpT2@j6z5S9aSA@e4atpq1YYjroU8TwciOB@3NEnWspwDLcg926LLJOFa4/IoN1yfrmapGUvHMCwPtDuMGB4gYc5jzBAVjyjyOhEdr3yEcLuMK@4Ece@CFn5KypwjkVmS@2ZiH@FesPRHKbymyKLqgzClZtJ5mHhWhnkYbFBDTI9qsDuA9R68odhqXmA5uaKmsyG3b3T2Cf6tcXfgIviNzyte8hmsRX@ckcLfm7jryMvCIiRvcoCNyI@vMZ/haTE7ngYuyrNdmoq3dnDl1nZV5f4r0WbJRMA@Ca34e11Duvdbu5e/@aXFTgwqfpamIPtY8cOi9VECPJBudjtVUumLWpGwjZsgJD0WrxIiBkt1P/5zTPoJQFUEyDIobytAbuZl3LoiRUOtOCASMprR/Jmq9wfdWgvpcihSDdUke27V/ZDqQxndhucsRvLikhS/juS1m@KlSXBFLPuT9dJUMTl3BWMz2Zdy4Sfb/jAGEagFbCbshehgPK/t@6jVmVQk/5iRW@ZFhFoQ55FcSuptijt@Pvcvmgw7XafKXLsC92oVlVf05TQ9kUyzcax7A4artS@Z7J8eYp3xvBPDWbDMiwG9RKbw5SKwDhFnuSRsCOY@XahiNMMP4Gyf7cO6DiFRTUeqngbPgGzPpINkLz7eqSbZ9uQSL2apgwnJWBkZe1@m/D0UtBDyWJulIK3T2kuZgDNv2UU8xpBSYE6tU5o9mksXiFUv15NbxKZcOPslTfEsM/nFAAK/1lSaFSnYvBbJiu6HDhEOVR5vrrrsA@8LLBiozpZOeQkGhPS2aritTlG4hf89d8VZXXoXyMAeXnSSljftegeyDmT@FJHsMrFdB0NxY7V2Wap6LxdgH8nvnzPDVGRW09Hhf7F72OXKWXD/UO8@qjXoGf9DeQWp4pwHfb7bCmVui625FpPa3auhKiDRr3HfAvloiBl1dR/3axaIOgUb7P9nHj9rtM558aDmLSMx/G@w/ouqRD44BmcJoyDkSck6@1EGkS36eCRMahB1TxyYfkDTnjXuwy7EV1NZWuKErOaJd3@z6MtZOyXF7aqs5l3e5FDY952Cfas3oS3O/YykcM/hXTYg7q907Qqh7Lh4ZJqqlZ1VL1rYzHtXftft8TzKwRMDHsXqM32pQWvjDSniIRaBirDVvohcHKYgmdm7pxm66en7XJ64BOgq@xeXvz1taIldNPIyFaXOs7V/UlaQvmtmSK0WyX0QS93BqEa@g3ZNgwJDpsPkBbnN9n@th9WqWlRvLRNIRj08qBsydv3280@m3MZr1AKV3rA82ExwZhFfl5aBqi09/Er/kYwalIw3r2h4ZqzoU5Fg3osykzJoYjV9GmK7VWaQwbNuljesbdsaWtzHmIxS@sTHevbxc2A/D6HJHfjSjG85tqydhdEHYANmtdtsyViOCM7r@@cGciPyTiqLZR8P9lvIOmsghdwFn/JPwnx9HHDuOO@bei0vAcuOJUUkrQdSSn/Da2PYNgyiRW7NitZT3WJX9g08Y8mMuMeLnC66dRfYohaMMK1Fhd5gLn8N49XM92HfAcpq6CuNGFVXl7P0PsaV@DSoE4QFiFa/nbW4G/JaaqHJW70aPMJeMVoVchlJ1k92LetaC6JlJdDnEsDVnmJ9hw4iW6pF3kvQw1NluVYLRbYVyF8jjj/bI3N5KSPyWh2ybMr41MzZJ76U6hnuP8oztuIeRhA/1Qqq8XmoOzIuylMq4AFNKZcRtKB1f7NqiAF211Gy2TL9ozw5idDrY9ctfHrR17S6sUUVcrq1eAUr9mL3@ZTeyeDiXLDldlofdroLjGcFayKlymxiug9Peh7qM00FaeajVnOodq8ag7j3jFQRILUL13kU5Tl@XOXBha54KxRmJ4n1CnG4VXg@kUXirMtCHss7zbYsRlPyDyTWPT9S15vnyHprqg4WzGsSoJXSSNAY3qgulbqn8a35JAdF9yuZ2LBapsgazclAjvv@AAY3ZfyYjz6Vxs0vE0DxDjYfzjN0kTYc5vSn4d/tVPOsrS0b7NTqjZglPVKoLhk1j2bb94LUgnIkbfqUmswaUBXg@hCGUksbJJgjbgbTLDoUO0WWEsopecBaDllJj47e4RRrLK2NOIDKxRgpeBU0J7TlLgbhu7xokBfHTYa59QAugrPC1ux9YffpQSbJR3kMv/YZjIygb0jllKqbGRDsD5J//2rbRniAr9y/UaZS7SBY8C7pNYKWLh5KMjkisQkhcJuX4shcSt9bWJYB3fTTuHyKJ8EZuvqgXtk@JuNtYfZjD8pZlpHrytytdFMw/YJuO0W2bm0ZQboBaLg9qpDfhj3p5ImnadNALE9txlso2epsGMuQMK8hbQzq609s9sYO@zxN2JC6Gez3eDo7oy8v7NH3Zb3C@GaT7/HnEfYjvFznfXqvFxIZr5lhUXr@1FcpCo1pzaWsMPpEnqWz8MCqz8516QYZWgt1Um@dMJtJdNv/Yg4uPuJJcQtCnkcTHvum3M9sohuvXgVe5L6KNGPXSpZ96A/CdSU3J42rYTuFXEmXs4KQ7UDszlpkm8YzsAY1ZRu61V3NWYdD3UhAHcXqy5zPc@qLlBjs2zJA1GtW4LOaAwbs7KcNEGWBdFoQc@1cQht/My6PrmgW1au38AzIdgD9Q2h0qP6ua0RaK61b3kvrPTFNJ3OMnaLcFpjnpUG8p2XEDNq4s7eE6aR5s2UuOiLlPXkeJ7@d44ki/CWy7oyua5VzXwBPx1z8tPqOXj/gnqI@XTZ3hte7ge7z3sJe90irOz2ROiSfrvBZWsVg1WZlpIP8eso58RUyZvLVBbJs3R8Fjs1GG7rBXzndxgZptB3YFyS85xIZ3iB44slzmk/dVfNJhAw47YMU2cdlIC@jzibQPMvhFWA81jfPstF9FnrypzF9fSKr3m65mK/9i6omLHcUtkPHZNI8iQQ4Y5OvD@08Lc/Omszhhf28a26BR5p7eKodwGnekAUbDHP6QzX1M/uiC9l2zm8pBQ0eqkpsYEKroYlQKXlX5Y506eshoDxm1IqHZ9VNec07R@7LDKKjCfj4i1feqEqOt5ktmjK8Gwn1dxAq@6q@y2r8Bq@uGkn0ydO2QF4FRz5OeI/pFAgyD2lDpCbfSi906wiCo8424GV9aOMRUlkRdGlWMX/rPv0H8mdWN5XHCroBAnuFeFd1udnRMLdkWHODjhlv4b2a/1qvHYh2mZA5AOV0XS1RjzzlgdEKGyLyMmDz0YPUXD0Jvln@NY6tPVn9SB7Qf2N@i6yVsHdWysB8VU5S5M0jWR6U7BDeG3hP5uBjT9nZvuRD652Qsd/A22aOHPseJlrO8GQ6ImFJ374hs@0ZGPZtGmKXF3GxhfILMEzvN15MmFi8ZbKqD8aUeVOL9G1GJphqXdx4O2CbzgL3qgqq/r6aU7NIyBTK4xHkS/Jd8Bt8v7FDrcGVm853jPtRxF0zRyfr0wRArSKvsT/b4/YjVFHISkU1Qj5nixh7mjpk8F/s82SjCbn2sKfGbViCHPAlTNFMb/iUzSExDTwty8ePk6kvRTIV2kYCDLijakhFb6R6FaI7oCpbSslDUBFgDQY6BvthIFMB@6fpUjKVM7AA@i496T1KyIC15tk6Iy@CMFHFYLfvqiXXkDtHjIzidVYQExO87e8DVbLVEhP7GzAJNRFYHt3jvjR3u0ECJbUJ/j@UyN3fzLMcSYH3CDTVuLyA9ZfPJ8hO02oNvDUHgjG01wq4FWjKTGRcTEnvkRwGM33tsL4SwEx4GyUGZSS8N22T3DnAYcJPeRpc1UI1/RkvF7hq86zd/cABwwGDREaAKH7J9svgbC7HMl9BRk8YHgvkLwDs6bQtPa5FMCKGgM3rTcxHmM54xgjg/ws/pgP43sQxvD13lBfj8v5TWH/M4tbRSMxCDv5d/UEVc5RtlRjhtGq2H/NAg3OyELGoukI1U8OX/INRLpc/a34cS@GsKU/IR8vhVyAJnSnIuSkbUbagryjiTnxlLzhzwDcqDIg3kp1PtgPlsQz3YjX8G0CPnQUmvHhF39L2gndULqgF3rlVksZuCvmI51P1fZy32I0vK3kEwbjr5fGUHqle02J/9lQsq8iC0yl5xG3zu8GPMoF12U1AZffVE/mr/V1HvCp9@AmWGS4@zGJiF1aAjeuBHwaqEVtA1ykZNmSF@bTX56ZdyfqBhwuGfVBG3j5qc6Gn4GsLeie0uA1f34nvOHDhuQ4mRN6pW/SPItla3Ic35N7HWb6s5yiUBHXfBIiYRel1C0OcDk/hY2oCf9MJDXE0J8/ibKjAn6etL5jYxxx5cfan6xGe30SueXZ2R@o8i2x3dF1vNcpdNuQW0o6POelLRMqp9PtwhjV3h6yxM2MadDEnrx3rE4y67ps74b456c4Fqr4fxh9UpRyb8miCedtut5zYCq0wAyvwos47vFMI5uu3AoIPb@WdkCawYslX1Z2qetbiORKfZcsiXv4QBJwHL94AFV4jPeDbZ3dAapsAOVDCZ@AnKV6/9wwrtuLLw0ie@GevmzIET38WXr9OzYHPh2pph7zYlHk/lIeuccaWWZMZaGSnPISCsSwWoicCUtoKbL8DVGQur8a/5v5KkXd6EQ1WeNlk8B15WBfyxWZ5lagSD1bAqBP5wGQff2@73N5KabIggxHPSkx8fz4n/TkZtM5GvOd6x7fwoFLYZiPQ51wIRAwCgncQkxvzpeZaV5m0XBr5IYj1oKwYqmrb0GvcjOYv/Tt53uyyvOCJ8eUdVz3YaMGVF@/n4ZmrHfpeLaRLpGOPd2gid/FW6H5273dzQ9nljQjgTsml1gG1EXhQl7A/rqRGY/bG@2dYTAHbq7n6PlX@ZkvtOvxL/8QNHKgWp82U5Z9YnG/wUsuqVkbs3gRNWeEGDY@4l/KszL32ZJgXDzX0ZYjxDVn6LuBFAs3gEsDIZHXyA933eG/9HjPehZEGF2LjCpIoFMMBVd28Td8F7e@P@bmpNlJugHjHGV4ZNq/PkHzPy4j62b7oMok12Us9c0WemWpEN3GcwQB5Dd0kXG@77tBrSnkz1uAJvsEToVuR4PRuUlVfBsBNigI8indMV1seA7C14jMwXZcv89YZxMiILwXeyNLnStcNm7fXyWCsr6W6g6fBLiDYZWQt0I07Utlg2fzGmBmweHMAadRwMyDV4@ERdityd2Ym4lH4Ji@4LGF9/HYWvmTxKG8mQg4YDEJehlzKs7gnS9ek9iFiucRb8Xht1NMDGJezw0r0UxPV5H1vMn8FKydFXk@UYLXmYTB2EM/vCBPvkj5dxwvN1zcmCiwwvVXjG3lVQgoY0ZmSeoeLIBxgjTTNgs19HgeS1xbcCcE7yNw3yB/ofxGp7lX/Y/z3oOGqeUDma8hB3v1YN/RfN0Ek5pOrAA7WPcH5ZjHvnmt0oaLNU64A3lWfnUalH9h2fYWtR42L@bQaize7vJJ8jOW94tdfSMnkTaIR062s6lO906m0vrZ4EdOZkcnNyA@Z//ipFP@fCBdb/yuEI1s@ck8faz9x8uyZjvYTF47ht@Ntl9oPnT55puNQ26EzHecunG3rOHfi2JmOtmOXjnRcPHah4/KhtvUP4bdrRzpOnLzYfvJox8mLZ/VH2i9cO9d@9tyJjkMXjvMpF88dutDe0XbtYus/D/GH7dcunL3YceTaxfZjJ8@4rf/Nwn86/rP/SHhk/X@wsLXd87P53M@t/8vCf661/SdwT5455v7v2Uvt5y61G1uMXzz//zly9gzfGradPe5dOHb@0skLxzz3iB6A64dHLhw71H7si0MXT3ju6aMb8JNL547iJ17rGX549OTxYxfbPffEsauu7//v/wc)

The TIO link includes some additional code to print the MD5 of the output rather than printing the output itself:

`ec73f8229f7f8f2e542c316a41cbfff4`

#### How?

This was compressed by:

1. Mapping the 20 distinct amino acids to ASCII characters 32 to 51.
2. Repeatedly replacing the most frequent 2-character group by a new ASCII character in the following ranges:

   - 52-91
   - 93-95
   - 97-126
   - 161-255

Which leaves us with a dictionary of 336 bytes (168 entries of 2 characters) and a final compressed string of 16161 bytes.

The above code is doing the exact opposite.

Comment: Very, very nice. I was going to do something similar but had to leave for a couple of hours. I think you can save another couple bytes by including the last `ylisoleuc` in the compressed data and just doing `+'ine'`.

Comment: @ETHproductions Ah yes, you're right. I'll do that tomorrow. (I've just switched to another computer and don't have the compression code at my fingertips anymore.)

Comment: I actually thought about doing just the same, only up to 126; but actually I had more important things to do these holidays. Very nice work! * bows *

Comment: What's wrong with 0-31, 127-160?

Answer (score 17):

## Mathematica, 319 + 14971 = 15290 bytes

```
For[p={};a={t={{{{{tyros,asparagin},prol},{ser,threon}},{{lys,alan},{glutam,val}}},{{{{phen,{methion,cystein}},argin},{aspart,{glutamin,{histid,tryptoph}}}},{leuc,{,glyc}}}},r=Join@@IntegerDigits[BinaryReadList@"b",2,8]},r!={},If[AtomQ@a,p=Join[p,{a,yl}/.{,yl}->{iso}];a=t,a=a[[1+#&@@r]];r=Rest@r]];##~Print~leucine&@@p
```

*Incredibly, this is exactly one byte more than [this bzip2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116660/56178). Can somebody find a couple of bytes to save?!*

This is a program that prints the full name of titin to STDOUT. We use the same structure described in [Jörg Hülsermann's PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116658/56178), and additionally note that all the words except for `"iso"` end in `"yl"`, which we add separately each time unless inappropriate (this is what `p=Join[p,{a,yl}/.{,yl}->{iso}]` does). We store the data in a 14971 -byte file called `"b"` in the working directory ([hex dump is here](https://pastebin.com/RRYHUYCi)), which is converted to the list of its corresponding bits by `Join@@IntegerDigits[BinaryReadList@"b",2,8]`.

That list of bits has been determined by [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), which is a lovely data compression scheme that takes relative frequencies into account; it requires the decoding template, stored here as the binary tree `t`, as well as the raw list of bits. Inexplicably, Mathematica doesn't have a Huffman decoding (or encoding) built-in, so that's what the `For`-loop implements.

Comment: Never would've expected to see a Mathematica answer here, nice! How did you get away with not using strings for the words? (Also, if I let this run, how long would it be expected to take?)

Comment: (It takes a bit less than 2 minutes on my machine.) All those non-strings `tyros`, `asparagin`, etc. are interpreted as undefined variables, which can still be manipulated by a hopeful Mathematica; fortunately, `Print` is perfectly happy to print the names of undefined variables, and also (super conveniently) prints whatever arguments you give it without intervening spaces, thus doing away with needing to 'StringJoin' anything.

Comment: What about the Mathematica function `IUPACName["Titin"]`? ;)

Comment: Also, I feel that the amino acids are a built in in mathematica (citation needed)

Comment: @BetaDecay Trust Mathematica to have a builtin...

Comment: What about `ProteinData["TTNIsoformN2A"]`?

Answer (score 17):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + sed + xz, <s>13322</s> <s>13290</s> <s>12785</s> <s>12706</s> <s>12694</s> <s>12687</s> 12681 bytes

```bash
sed 1d $0|unxz|sed /`sed 's:[A-T]:yl/g;s/&/:g'<<<AvalBglutamClysDthreonEserFprolGglycHleucIisoleucJalanKaspartLarginMasparaginNtyrosOglutaminPphenylalanQtryptophRhistidScysteinTmethion`yl/g\;s/yl$/ine/
<12479 bytes of binary data>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#XZ3bjm65VYXveYp9AQIkgrx8WLZRxJPkxkeRCyJENyI8ffi@tQNBpNPdu6r@Wgd7zjHHmAf3H/@4f/zm33/85t9@@fHPP379/a@//8M//vIvP37729/@@N2fanrLm2NIj/@MOYW6anlPbXXwpz//NN43/O@fa01plJmfuEsuO43a38Unapo1xRvfeNN4a6xp@Vd@6vs@78rxrS/Xrpmvdk78udeUM1@3Grn2fU8u3qXG/NbA9y6/Vb/f6m/K7V38rPCn/vKb/vTPXw@vz98nz/epqQb@GWvOy3/z@52f7L/8hE/@/N6pmWfgPjzH/b9P509L4NPtdS36d/XvDuXhdyK/Ffjk9RMl8imeh6/7m0t6U/35VfmukrmaV@UzviHr@OfVKuvnen1fZ77Dp98SbxhlB/6X@fv@v/@FEMfzxNV50zZCviM/Z4zMe5eYWL1nzt7jKaVHti@m0p8TWAj26J7nslbhibHM1Pz9uFtbTwudX@Oxn/n09L5hPe98nj7Crju8oWAUYfdbG5fjfc8dN/OrO8572CH@kU59eLSzd6gzvGPe1DdP08ao5bn1Seftrfd9WYven/qctVq9fG@XGc6eq9TBi5W2x2KNW@qLld2H5UizLRbjjHZHHHOG8ZZZVp69xZnf9ZyT05o5vLWnvJ@6R7ip5PY8Ob95PTfNONKNd44@r2/@PLOF@fD0ZczFejY2JLeD0XFvLvi8Le@R8vu@e7TZx3pzTumytqPmO09kydI5vbe02pvKmXX77zeG8@7S2b7ILrQbcIfRGk92dq3PuifmW0s8p9z93hbrKvjZjjWsFd@e5zx1zFP63D0vfgWzSwXjv89uZ@h6D@b6DDYs@tpjpPCWXBdvldjDHLGG2/jgGKxnz2WEGbFLXquxMJEfxThxy/IGzKFjc7OyDfWdsWe8K0TWo2UuxDvW3PPJo5cU91Pm6W8dtz9pJvaz7fbwni9GyYN0tuoUNm2BF53te848/HkkdhlfqaO/8@a1w@rXp@0B4ziTJeaqO7EOAA8uNOPOrMHbC47LnZ6dd@aNNxZ4yx5jncg7lFKw03bj3rcNIOzeUgCfWFiMeutiSTdGkwb7FbL7EUp7WguDJ2DJcj819n0OnscqNayprI3HjKd13K2e8Y5yKqv9Dmy84/M3fsu4@goYJ7dtL4uRYwRBn3PTSfMkLT9yj9NPyvPGDkzx/L2UhCeNXC5GeUDTNwCO670JW@68MEs9uSQPyru@B4x92QO8Em8qmbcAv7hqSw3zGemNrc7VsBxQ4/DWYe2Zki/3AhE7dDwXCORVJm51Vrn9sths83s0wRcD5CHz6fMpKdXYxi7tZkCg1RDDbfdgWGPhdqNG7Pvlz6w2nvfsCdSxQYFrLR4gYkK4WHtrxdj7yHPzduzJ4iHwQ7a5hBla2/gBd6igSMFTQclZDpuNG3QekaUaWMbyUXvFSPO5dY6ZeMdY4@L5MBKMILFAE7AauXVQZM@B3TU8EYTL@PhTgxFigHzvuISuCYwJP/j9zbUkUChE0BenXE8W7GqPBTdbG69cO79x8z1Q5elPZmVmy4n7cHVe7Ak3RpBKjK2uZlq80bkN6MGI12iYBbs3xpg9ja27vrwZCIXh4HHP6Q9gASwSWHrZbOYFY4jGCSycoQRgS0u/s8fOTxpAWV68DqwjNoF8a7BvBUerK7c7N0/Wzg66eS/1vrG@Xn4TYGauNRfWPWFMNyTsNwAqPEKeIYMxx0Ay1@3rFmHlIeY23gCDwkaJE/xiAGFux7XCgiGcw7bffJ60Nf6VWNe9Jpdf4YSTCS0AOy4MsGA9e/JzHru3AngY5fZO7FImFFcw7@TGn2sHgNZ8ZmTXZgSIQuuVMLzAZT2mNkDlxWlSy8AtO4y99op9nMNW7lXel4iGfxDDdz9h3xn6JK7l3sHEF84Cn8Eticl4zloZ@316vYUwwKO3lELBcVn0/jTjMRjEQmBeROiBl717EnzY@5wfMaef5wm42QMWNq48Li/Emt1CgNggzxuPwAexaUZSvOqw6PyrjTc1ucU0BFbM57TCa6WzAo6M1eeE6T4DfB39roNbbN4un8ZOlFsWsMRSgcBgLYYPHFzAAxplGB8L18EMA2xgAazs8BvnPg1P1SKhJyCjLuu6rDD3EwivI7aAWwAjDxByn7esCHhzS54aGCBkH8lFOw2IuBCChT@XDhpGPhXWGJ0HwpliwmS4GviJR0X8CB8GQggABfAHUrEcaAgAeYHeUQqR92ELuKmk6MU@6xBecdoE9eL/b0wAHzdpMMn98sXGZXHnxJXnYPExY5yrE@YWWMnHJ7T15n1xoSRYJQI/vw/PDdrXw/4TPWBkqb/jJcCFtsIGrNigFp/U2nkmPAU7gF4YUp4Fq8PjgXIDbA9zxOfwsPjnHJedgqDcs0Gn1CNOg8cvHB2ecyFdp8UDmrJabC3cMYEhvBEctC2IRmC7MPCEaXfw42J3LPCcQBgLFCZhAroG0gFLuFHobjkki1VgSViu2cGD11AL7MftL7r6JdY7GxhSsEHiYjtJZnYkF5HHgUpElonQDIlpgA7IlfbY29uCFkHauyFLhKtCKIbQhAgLPBKAA0VqcFoiyH24cJyJa04BsxGcBlQJg8cyWVjiSya2bTyJQNzuNjzdxGKyJfDnO9a4xLK8IrysH589oRBWGrCmA1AvNME0KoOhmRV7oYEFNMYEMNa@IxCOTbouCxY7hEjcMWB/4WHDse4BQh4Cyhr78JxAT5puCqbZuPIAGWRQcNqNYSyuS9CeEtGJKy3ejzi@Ni5fcYQN5QK/2i5EcHC03jFLH@/hI6DRhRMcmAqbuNfe2iCmiGngkeAkrK5ikmAd4A0IYGiw14yfPT/ZNhcmvMU@2Yii3sIlsE34SV6AB0ogPEgljA7cIXaFXQQKQj@vVrkdLzPLzflmAiB0rlbCG1G@hffuvRqRJ6PaqpR@ErzYkovGgSTOBX5CslkEHY@4z@W4mCwBW9/qkFM3awdvfQwzqBsexDiBrS6Y1Zz5sPZnwmrubbDSkTFAnxLgxyW2XvSwR/3hA3Ai6NpzcVxejh0nJITle1SgD9ISFy4SFspiAtfP2nXJ66CUeCnB@XsRwHVwFTALqgcgsRjt8zFwioWYsE3UQCn8vK4kueGR2Aiok060S8D7CaUYO5TpgUU/bDpBhjCNokyRgAC@7X1w2UGEBVJRUwcNBP8fK6c48M2F0bYNjcUAxLO@OsEMkxtiHKY79sDC4M4NjEM8Q/bwtwKiZHSYN0UgTa0C1D7Ao09zAHu2aOaiRJX8RdwMN6mYGWIMAGX/CZVImgV5mRBtFgB7vPAlFBC8DzCCEmGuxFbWB@jGSIhULDPybb3GfH85RHacW9cS3AU0GLbLAx@@1HlaZDU7JACxx08J8iJn/uQRITnchVx7NUJwMWO5D5F9YN6gpsxKkWIaAClQQbshNWfjQJBCYC9ows0iLi00t5CIOxW6WLA@aNJQTgjX3PetENlWYeFop65pD/UO9v1CvEAowgIgBNwRQGEAUa0B/5iTAAqVvg2LrTgA9wsF6sJXwBFIAM8XXuASwhm84yxuiArANZuxIOqCQEXFLg1vfAH2Pwt7WITMBx7x7pNhvvhSIIor3yFjuBbODSRyC7aQVUGOQDcitoQcxPfVTHIPHPbLRqCzieobKCrrlDigf4nQCBV/1G8ZjzQomFbgJQdPEc63LxvnzAVK@XKPBzPJbGTG90@AxeFMeCmqaqErGtJj3AccRe8iqaQdlzdIuPnca/CyD3dvRJwiBahQCXh@MRcAy2dD@QpZpZRYEKLFXmA9@nuQnbAKhDSoKkjFfQANGF3GjHQqyMqGqoHebMJN2YhpmMfudi0ErlXDxYeINg2Oih/zwxcazoLxWuiTHnpHvoJvF4YBJKA/eU7WBR2EVIEXwzNYFOwNA@CSAZadFSzIbaA9HWgEOAXEQ68SPgK1hmYjJ1ol0IJ5@DtBgI2D@GAhyKydKszcdIkhC4b6oBUHrzDgIlo9jtAQxaadlmsECCyBx22NqPgEQ4U4Q1yhqCOzDRf2AAU@fRCXcE1Atr6X4PpskBSyvU9HsKLdYIrEGxwOolEF6cDrDVjQyHUG0D7lggiD0W1wBoatHgJ9G7tIyAbTeMkBdeXG7zHCwyV4ez119IpuRbewiEh74h2rw24fHu3GymsDgMqaNDrbWQda7RnIxS4L1rsRtnj22Z3IwhO2/qghC4gxCzIT56tciGVsBHV4PnQU2bRdxg5ZBuSSgbjnhbolnkJn3gLu44ZgAjbDKi8sdbgcBPgUILd3@3Koizf1hDIhfBNaatSFj7EQK2frK9wdHCMmsgIInBfZyePUDuw8oF4jhF1daLDmeRU@c6R2MDNggJ0yNwJnBPGQXQTlB/plMGOJoBv5IDyS4hnZKNjiH@CUmgjBhwtuWBzchM38Mg3tJnjYYftB6cb95M3bCAJsvx11ZWTJRH9uAXFoMi04BgzubMWxYDobAPrxMFYERsnvINsIh4F1B9VhKSASi7p5lAoPItg@04CAk4Nr3OmZCcvOUgTkHNSI@MWDRThv1KvCzh@NXLjVA1011TDMM4HXOAta98UT0D@h6mrEPvCXO/YOSIHRxAnkPp/Fkc228OKgNGqOZQSUFPKLUImy2vMuoOHBfkolykg40IZNiHj7FxcNYawYN4a5XtYLdaHvjxrjl6aDfgxWyYQlWxlgkAin@xLWzD/2@gLxW8EN7D8mBIgft0GdDvw2AieF7cD7YW1I9sc8wvSZsumSGFowcvDKX/J3sDJwJkCDANYbK/cgDq55ESTWkJga4FeHfuT2sBQBtonb3F0UfRcZCR9q3AgLxSXehJpD3vCbkdt05DvQCpl33TqqDfo9fTxUeNhpQI5fyDUOWYTikia8GbbREStQI5zwcAcgHcc8BSsB9rEmzBfsxq5YBVSR6XjuA0@YRM2OrIAgnAdifl9sClIPPeEqldXEH1D4xNfwsNwVkg/oP2eDaxDCiaPwzru1zSVGxImRQgiXRHjjAVAlqAe@sloANZ8DsRMPNmx2PL6gDJiBMOHlMON3R6D5PYlwSlAsCxlFNAKD8a4cjLrsFqFP4sPb404sX/@yHNgJoeaRc5kNIFrh3EDFqY24XTGivdCzhKpq5s1FwaxAP4LVRkOjgPIDc4cJyNaPqG7qoRzggICUUDLpSrer8RxCgD7G1vAgYuKY71CTttgSK6qeW0I8AhzKgYoBC/tHcqEAZtXzAdk2fqL@7zBedWREP8IccuJFEFwDBCCAYkqVlcHgQDbC@YU@rmX@YcPGC1HyiWunjWxG63eRafPOT3nV9zd/4kHid0076vIXmTTKNhEOE2WXoSawbbxMD4J8Z9bNZDQsjk0l0rymz5DtPLLZ2grKbQhfVwaOBOAQYQbrRQB8zcJGg3b78ldmoSBNBDp1PmBngjvwZMgxnBr@SLAvMDnUBeRQdABX3gRm8y08IPOw78SQiYeg/MAsoeEgDWGwbpahQqbZOJgDkRL2QOwjCpieqgSqatLiMZvMnSGBl4eusWLaDZVRL88MZXmTEAVSC0oVdgsK3Zor3rk7aFtVJHeg4kHlAeeoeaxQc4DmomSRTQ8sEKlr1jU8oRysLUFqMOiMZES7pc1STqsa@MdjbqUcjG0ZT17kwH54@hcRAWYP3hpByw0ggTN4EcgTTJcrj9osNwC6Yucbo7nhBqkDFt5SE1HCrPcaA5LWVWu8LmEFPcPzrq3ogjAVKZtACcZO2AuBaBVICntNaEP@wPwmjxNGia4@avwL4hAegkgcJWPtiy3tSKiIk@KJUIUjh3tvkDYQHAj8tcB7edQEeINLpXwVsce8fSaQsLmrmT3pPBKWdnGKDjDCs6FHoDCLJ8/H9kBOXDM8Zrpr40urWyhprLe3Yo0qQ3ngogYa6CkuiFgfmaidkH/VGDvhhKjXzWbIA6Cg90SWk/i162N6Ei1czbHwXhNq8ATJy@Yy0Joy@di7AqLfBz5FEootEH8G3gP4Ha42C5p0mhHnmVldaK9Lh68TfVnne7G7ZBnAvHZWKmA7k63Lb2UBWReAqkWAFNxlLY/6By2X0osyAXbibe50zzxtyYpXkYIgDXgW04agcJFhXAQkGH1gWw9rwKcCtoy@NfsBkKDRYAeJ1RoEYSgtzA4h499hHVjJudY7eoL1g1QvMTjCSB8uRxiAzBE1twk5EDv6GsmUNuHqtXRG@AOn0Tz67bz7KV@G@TEQIq1N@xdes6OE12Hp27Uqk/Ym3qeuriCQwN3HABIX@gRRgP2wlhA@sAEoUVMkswqVQG9pJfEdpdVO0zxjNUEOE0B2HtYDA@XeHXrPz83@6iZ1oSwRCEOBuzsQuOODm7IcdROlXiC2sXuz47WPibXDalt7eAuwYD20mKlnK9KGMQAmIHAG4KFUxk7QdQLM6Fjoe69gFxxJly9EJF53qEEPShmmgIFvAjDCB194CmIhNGOu9gnSLZ4U7owzgzTI0wd0S7B3K4jzNUuFr7QsohL2J4gHBUEMJWUL7AHu04kVBCqTI1DjUPk06/vA@7A55EziKToqF5MDRSHyCcjwjarFeAzKd4UTg4nYPsuvzkN6dxaVN4GY4k6YMO8MPS6m1ogm@PaI1nDwC7YL6iKisAyoTksiHe1DCFoBPYb/zMV23MMTEzAX0SBiVptd7Bd/mvLbDoF/kS2wY8VOPFxW3MM@AUKihvocFWE2YJjCxE70JORU2ALFOxC/8MCJR0HxCDynXp75ltGVoy@Pl540QXEisKkd8BCSVRpRDAnGcuFXM0xIzVc5sZoDg5csdTZgGhuI6uiFCWcoZmL5l3koLapb93pQdA2AlnArV9JaA180kwE1hUV1EHNjiEBPrtuUx0LuW0CIEIWBkDApZM0Z5mhZjjXkoVj9EyfIrsLAzCAuuAdchBhViGPFGlghFkI@iXswm69sWCEUcVjl2TzTsyNSFvIMR0E5FxgqbMFaKsELuXHeSIT8UmQ8QGsEw3rUU0QpWKqwmNCJtyNUIPbE2HGIsZHwbTEIGjORAQAKlnDhHogU1njPaemAz2Kg8ctqgVUyUgR2gaQib7DMe4FHfIoAAza8@flINbB6WNDX4kAGIaGQ@BrSl6drqGlf7UsEncdSEes@NKSRzgOjBmAS5opA4iV4loUN7mBgrl@ZGtSIAwDvFkhNH3EBxGfpNRB64LVv47FNPZ0MyYMOTHznqKiBHEg9e8DLyOtKGxUs523CSC0kWFTLmj8c6ypiWZpm/LQ8jSegmADwtyknoVcYY/HORIqjQUS5n60hhF0QdPYrtBcYOsYFIEi6MPHWYN8suaQSlIdPIzEQc4d1GU@zagoSYAkHEcXWb7R6hRiegNTIMKJLzEZBCI4NzXSbrBkuC1CaqLP@cc@DuAgVgQD8IbiIso8ZTEjVlupD4t@GrDHhzDJ8RZcF@xKK3bJOGI4psubPUR2BG09fogyOgSNcEfTFy5QS4OQM/bUlaQBeHfYHRKIJAKw1cZpkQftBS4@AitI00RSW6tD7zRohpsWKRyI5WgapNZB3tUJeE/wySKVxrYp/PEgI0Hjbo3EFrBRPwrzQH6iqRZxD7ST11QKshh0g7EQBvlCy3Fd@S6yJ19oXyAZL2HgyLJer2LaALIUa83Uo4G6EUAAfF30VeZBn8c0@TJtZHC2GbQwYWUKsAMDg0RixCVzZRkMAVf4Fx5Bn8NRweKQKS2wDlnQMOgEPwJTxfJ4PsczNTaEgvdA4KHciCW/yICTQknxMEYRIIQxePAau87CpxBmE8ECwoJP7TYByPmCFInk8G7HLckfFJ0u9BW6IG5Cbv4Iiyqybr8vS2sESWnsp6T3XZ7G3yar6/pBIVYCvP2AwmN8t7y5@1MpzD8ugv6tnLqSgfkmEF2iD7@D5AMyu8NltqwibQNhFDHeLNhg@a@yOWsbl/Qc2P/Fi1bHNRvapoQvKRJKdCXdAFyHLBhdHkyOrTZRBuHj5herq94XVVhhzANiMDPAafAoxwGNtq/4IHihArF/dk19R@@KaqJM9ulwX@M89hQe2giEjVl6U87HCSyBBKTbrfvdChfVlXq0MsAOdPpFTsC2CBxsAlEOVIlZCQIKM4YdIGyIuKgkqxiMgCIe1/GDha0EeVz64OW6LJ@FL6RisJ1bKK/UHe8IMUw@8AhIe2GLz3hVxwIg5Lsud1pNY4idAy9jlCak3A3gCcdSIB6sgvoPgyL6OfWd026temteKEd4OC7tqDn4HPEGXtlW5WmgJGnpCSIOnRapktvXrQuQJCEKYNNCDpiFSEQzZzG2Z@kHoi2vQUWBkWIGM364S50D7jj5/sLFHWoRQnIMIud7NymLA1xwfkRa5Rugfr0nlYdkYt@XqcBTz1Rn7A9ZQN4iQG8YDSUf0lIhJ47sIUOAPFd4E51tcGbDFrgU2MIYE@BOxsgGY21sAclsAKNB5xZdtbeYtCWi3QESFJiJAqzBQ3LNZiBeHYD4sFupynSNzMmGbbazbpmzmQFiYjMvs6ZXNwlmRlWXgogH0K8qS5wI8SwIIkMBFwgE7CID2CcKEAXHu@PIUz8T6t@zoIDEh2Kem/vX@DCtlvNNUo/ntZ8HK4co4w@q8AdIQBHmh@wNrfjrIaftC124hngojrCkThJG1mE8HWmy1gCDBx8oOkGgFLdZxs/Xg@VrGyAhdhE@Daz22aiCbcE6MvCDfMBJQis8TUwhvW018tlUuNTnejAnCaqAvFeR0r5CObwSxA/SH5XAlAGngi3WxQDsts@TPZLbfO1khDEPFJ94KRBDbksVAE@yEKDDRxpXJAl7TYJhebUQs2wPHQtjBhc5CF3bw0TY9VB0Ckg9HLGiFaf3MDsr6foHOWpl9BaibiJ8905whcR8kDmqOpMwH8EAW1lWcZvehSaDtNPkbun1W56C1DlGt826PnZQQPLjaZE3hzlk@@aLMMGv8usr3Jt9OsOmy8AAs2tbTPIatW/DLd5hFvoTvB/ky0YU3Ah9WEi/hcebyjAzmQ5pTxjCNb9kCJQ@CiYSCJsJkghU1m5LP1egJWPwC0DBMicraj/lrlBpvyHLB8BYcAKKyw02iL0FBPfhZy8YiwX6gGD8mbrXbJqyf8DLYavwWSzIjhemdaF3L1kZDehnXHEa0hH7AMJt9IL92WmHaKGG8AyaN9rKzZ017RFghgjLb35akCjFAiL3ZPj@A3TVMsH58VISs1uGgFnyIl0aSQQgIEkAD4iWYrxhWEr/UAg8FgFsi7jYJo0FgJhID@LoJYHO92SgB3IQteSSyoa2JZQ8wctnrQFy/KUzUMWhyV8dSv/I/i27jSkVJNXOCr8@UcxMnvlaWYJ@tfSUTq2EJ@eRneTHa/4zFVMQsjAtIfXLyMR6QqjzROIK1fH0sj1kdIiU/YQcIGMQfHuXLlIxs8rxi5dkuxK8DBGHZ7Ww7RZfZI7SmLZhLC7hrGfFAe9AZl5VF9MDRoWpQxG27NCsD8bK9FJBHfk9s015QwgP/jnDO2hG@bBNW/1pqABlRxwpy0KkiQm8ST@wNxvrKow7pl/VAlNiYUCsE5idxWzDExQocUIqli/AJrCbAn/YRT@dXCRqQVoJls0XtpqG6swkRLawhWIhE6CwWnqeG7NvLBxriegX7Qg3ZX/cusLn7pjBEJD5xChixzxfmio1Buglii93nkQn0GZCYdjAC5vjxGcgG4B4igqbPPG1RFfG8gysnKGgiullUyChlzNxmHYJ@J6KycxvmNRGYvAbbYWacwLyriogPyMK5BhcpmHDg@U06YH3bv5oyZidpBhIagMvDBqtQTVfj/eD/zUQwsNZOzAYVslfEsKK@C03xA3NUb1uFTRUOiaxFUSNwBcbHSvQEDa3VW8ludk9vE2JEjIuiwCMudLjfahfEMoNSIETPx0qgCGeaeeL3rogAbWVNJLbFZCrAFLEhbM96QLl2jC4YoGVjMPLYd3xqd66C3e28I/v81VbiU5Ay0cxIgYMiPZKTAkA@AintbxIj2@6LYuMiC5yZ@okl3W3JFE1BfJ3SBZTlMgk6d7SwgQeEx94Coi52eqRYlpVVsKypKQ8bnUCx9V4CPq4O24sBHwta2UXDjmJQI4ZwOTY/V5idic3ebDxlhzABm5ZN0QIs@N4k3NmByIIgdHhAKEeEH4H5yGvIxwwICWIMOh3ZxzWJNJahlr3RCjcHBYBMhK7oYu8HROU8b4ILwBrbvcusgI3gduZHe1YCvBfVipLC4MdjY2grZl7fhA3KPsDKO0AtBMuAFF0Dcj7R1qm3Itywgq9xCmwZE6/E/gG2rKSKENCE30dho0hIEbBET7UPmGwilmBx8lcP6EF@CRUFvWz5IOzCvsYbxrHvwkR5@RpXQUqCAEosWWuHwGAa2RoYVokyIhhY8tqYXTPkdF7tNJPaS0Fnc6uwdr5ew5aseB9@OIg1xLC9pNedOAuwYobNxogC9z/RjOprk9hD5PtoECtIHMStVJkzRYvy9obYqsuj8A2EmnV5gvDKg4XGm197U@A5cVjnZyVCZLcyhgS2iAlgDVuN3av/CXLFMi8RLNq0BINu0AUlUK9l2XDy2G24Vge6RCZxWrFhtR@FZ3OvVbdkbwUqnmfnsQl1DaU2I7L8sVcLZAb@Ya6oFrg@10E3RfbSGSNr3vglhmZTKL@XiNw9d/FBOSiZATmrPSN1I5Ogkt0ZFH4PVm24cf4BZckniSXD5kmzs72Zkgu2KSB5LVMcpQrPW4H/aLPnKAlpgtJxrGp/ffawSOs54MFaFyCC9UXREWmi8uTRYjBvhbLVx22og8iukiGO88ICrCxafUhFBGfFC6hRid5Tj55qlfx5PWwv@7SmT@wAcidkyOPYOt0zfKDBMqyDEwWgbfBN@aNtlYijNdb1VgcByraElqHWgefEgGEaOCw3lMLZm27bGWLKKQAgen3W7XuDbF@wBTkhJgeHUK3X@w1a4WUb62JjlolQCTILVSz1fgthyci81DK2EAruA60ZKPPXZEUfc9nVZx3nZys@gAFnIJDYyQDqHHvBMgiH/QL@OPhxQwmJlsashy0ZkEkKQgeaO14AJJjzNyPn@@79xGwqrsdbEaiQexCYdcLRXhOHl9AMyiJKrCXvZcWeR9dYFng9pwNeB00BaKERyr7JSRBkwwO5OGwSUWg1eN01mXTRIO83CYOJ6NPZ3nDYyEasWW7ojkUYq89L7OcJr6nmR5kyiUq2kWa@797bXQiLXy/Uin3dZaxoTV6@ATEmVmfCZxvIo7fBaNgxSB4bRviZNrL2rxjCawcYJoAKKl3MDYC1va/ZFKntTucx0NpAIOwwPnDTzZJ1ay8NkBsOz1ggmB17MZ0KsX/mrNAi9gQ6M3nlaqOLcJRAF@R5ujd@dY2sE/SKOlSwW7nj9Zc9DIRTCHSq5VHM1a9gDvEB/9jdbfcnOw9neR6AHgPMzUBlC4maPMzHApf1tv0062dmWolZZgJc8SfYQz9M88Ru3yOiNU3bv7nJc7fNc1hcdTgN5hbMM2EEbysd58eQnEODI@BKB0E6AJQEieyIxrlxICQoIkJH5eHs2yHaP3B9@MWj2doI/6BusMMIEcOC8CSYMfi6RSbcyGbATjBeUKiwPgYOGP0U118iIzuGSbhDudmiBrZey4s5O1i0DI7F@joUxD0A0dikCBkdUFRTbxXuCqdEEOATLwoeoWj4H/wRgSvNLN2O8K9B4PbZUBWJyBMhdLyN/WLI/W21C30Bt8O7uQ2fA3lukDQR/ZozVuvs4uhi@0YqwcSVs/2wQU0F5KDHmsOInR0q6IOQEljXWB/QzlkicI14FQ29vCv29mJqAUwxG95VqYjezjVKcBrDIGiGHCsaJtCjLcHr3NlQ@NXOyToQSo9lOigjPBLOjhyEcFxJ@y0d3UkIiBtIRzIspMXZqJZtNWVanucF7AoqzWC0gI134qbHHt4dWUy4Sgd0TCQTvZvN1fDe2BQxduU1M5cQ4aklXlg68emYacLvH9upP8sE4zG649hY/roiAxFg1iKZg58iTm6SPMyv5xTs5JusHdExfrWZNLhak0zYC1udrhh2smDel9tnO60dYRzWziF44FjCe/kU28JCyCRUstaCUHw7OGJjmxk6FTEG1cSOYR5EPcJoqUpT5YWdLopjp6iIgK53QMsarB1OWmbOvhlSy8UOudlvxVvlG7@b2v8vI8IMDfIThkskw5mBVcNDIfIAv8nSRiJYlRcFb8PcsIMYAEo201Y7PTG4@I2k3GA5IQoV4Fb46sRn5D1Tt6Yt5EIpssEALvFYargVEoAQjWYIvx5RcPbDHZDc0SHpw2OvYQqWhQ8Rgeg44FkJak8gf10MrAbj402XdZg@bUSaT4M8IcXBZ2RuSihsZDmibRCFsK7lbNUnxwdLj7jA8M422xfNEyPjidsvPNhxowvimNhwcvu6wRcWZcbDMVvIepbLvTBgPwmy9Mh9LGfDFdpX@nL8LnyNQrNo2ef8jBsOGBBWAerHeUAYokM6iFnsZ1j9Ah3ApeHgFdxIpD@mYJ7jtPBbucdi/9DOkmli4RscY7SpGyY7YcG1OSuFxPTiUAFgk6Dymp8hjIXxwhyAGfB5V/ihWQqQrPDoy5cazog6MpnRdDFY8knjaxEC5ogo1YQBS0mQWddZIhv53sZuhuYsztdiXAhy8ZrHBYJQMdFkMPoNeXxQ7NE5Wt7GFDkA/ToRetZXs0OxVYeT8Ey@mXH@8NpayoZYMbbF7JpcR1ETNGG3d8tU57WvfKhYQfnBRzvcA9D94AA6xx0fFrBZsDziyX0/6os1NQelbLYqPMyEwORRzZDZ7uk028PHkDxw5gOml/52i5HEYjYxogDu3dcJTtulJICONRBPrXSshGAFuR1CmW/K4Jw9d8R6@A/CShfgJ3rW49CZCcZmcZIgSVBATh4b1Xn9WFCdYB4yeNjCLo5/bPqrck8VSZJG5Qh5LgG9Om1zfWzmj4aAOBzbg2E99hvYBoU543E5D/uFG54reBYez8lWBxsRRMY3aThGp505M1fLa@NEeuytgxLgM69zOyy/jfeaB3BMyDzigxPAlu4KhktUK5ZjUD9IKxt0ET3AVDFfxaos7Jq3fGwvn3KVy@6zIQlghT7w0P2YYHCSiY86SwOfRg1BtmCGNjxg1YnI//qpyR0ccZbLoH6azcKQcvxo9W9asRLjUBzTIfxcgpm/gzmNJ1mN3OYQX2dup4W3Y@7B6g7UU724TGoSZAnU0EjuFqMDZ@i8hVaoZqtivePjRK@m73RFttfVqXF2had0RpPHj2ZR9K/Injk1gm7mt78C@exfCTvF@SGoLQcpqf5tidbJePdM6LFm4dABlLRhNdOWv4ebRFzu46fsxOuoEjRhvetrvoJzZNv14YVmeh3Kj/bRwyqBSgjCsWc@I0WhIBBqq8JmUa7KfcO2v0ayZO2bx1J7Jhiy4ci3A8F584DW5Rln8YgI8QdhNm3K5xbARX9tGeCqMLGzm6NJbI15Y4f7IUyweJzHAWQoGmJacsXOgX657eiFEt4CZen2Uj7Dhpdq5qSinp2TqbACO87MLLTuNKlV7wdXhdh/ucrmtEeCisIwirkg3AV2eBFuOS9HJ5x6HI6B2omW1vWiPMhuRm2nx65Nv7ZzWkQJUY3UnITyZIX1tcLuauIp2RO2bmnoHncZFlNFPEdfa39llWwWrOCb87wE6CSVqGJtsGMou/uIWcMrgW2acf6qIbCHYhMhgJjtxc02CS1zVNBYkOoEY5TNm2iF@jord27w7IQa69dM7Jg9xNcGqutYLiIVHsAN4ATE15TV/LgdZM5W8wBqEjRqMugceCjXynAjJ3D3@7XGcdtWjgNNzeZrYidQbH8UuwYII/nQOxe1VeHg2WwTZv4a9R3f385kF8/igPUV2yvQEKAxIfk9ybaVWVg4fby1pQ1iusvaGlB2LXoSFow//ipOhmsCITY@qo@JkMfWqMb2XQzaDMlAfPA1T52dRwRtss0a72p@AhoT1zcDRvy9zi113hpKlMV9do2Aj56dCmh7tnnnGx2RYmkCqlSCC@CgV6GeJzjjDKda8K2P2HXWBo1g@SA6Ii51HtCCZmvhkd/b8/LgJKYzrflDnBob8X4a42Etigc@EEKgMnsRWvD1K9gLFmmbPBHXROLrWDey@7WUFs/X2jI6tBbwzYuVGcciBNLTI2fwZkdH18Vr7FfDKJqZLgjGt2wY20WA2i/coDR4ne3Fb4rG1vqYcAcdnTeu9@pXEEDLZvAWSLkN53fnn/0djniYHEwQkOhUpdovwd7RENf0uceUOKC03mTrCXyP4ITaMK9QlnXlJFzYUfj0p2JAnp/SzIM68mxh2D5D7MpK/mI/at87YI6y@EQQgn2hih9bXzFy1JgwYfvHtcus2J/21I6NOoYL/STMgeK9O/YVA1T2yKrtqe0Qe8@JQJuvYFL3O84HcLSoBTYsTyR4@R3oG29pach@5uz/Z7O9JZ5p9i/GT3ddCF9OjmzwRlCdghuZRkW5YbHgeEVNB/tRId22OdoWxNYSbAlkvMo3vAKLS@DuwhAwFoiaWIkZ216BWkksgCXkuocjhVgNMRKikiJBdEe4yMLiifHTGsF1cBWY4u7vPqp3UB688CmC2UAoB4A@tJNNLHwXCzgcV4YaJKOx1Sx@jwi4wzdvtEJ4PbXgqwDyZLgcWBK4mqdQILuJrUQudnp6nIKt7whkIhfcZMKuDbIeWOPWB6zLvqSBZH5b/LKiMb32qtlPDyL6cTyp82JcG3YVDu6I9GieGIEKtHC4g83pxawBeAshmub@iQSDJy/jG3Mqz9gPAflLx2QP0unIw3qQ0jacR3vuB94DfNumjXNfk11LYeGsSLb/G0pihk8y9U7jJMzQ5Ds4bzkdbSLMRfQCUgJSCOVmmyEeBNvQrUFoOuw2YUlFdk11dEeizbBCsKNH0YCyBT7p8QjTkf1gg7zz7DZhz/JJluapFY/nqGToFcvm0Cch1AZ5PAn2mexmNG2csgO@LmiwuerZ6MZgb/W0uah9nV9Y3BEV8NPYBXz32JO0YGpOLya4sHUPxzNO/SokWGhwbH7w/tU3NuwHcMrTSyYRC3oZhrlYp26JpWPCGmcOngSDQENWRAId0q1@YYwwZTkob4uskCFrFGmg3UJAcL@Ap9Qba8FVEQqw1gCPZzcHgUciH3G9BUaWggOgRNFKziBAV0fPmKDi@KDZeNcSncQ83UbiYrqXZ0deQn0eCPuAQx/c5eJkQNZrgUIs6PzwwBe@wxyG0QEPtBhF7IDUY88QT1Y6TkB3yNgToeqaTMVhEswPjooif6AgPIE9T8P8hz3D4F03@ySROp4rwjXzne9dHo7Q7fWD4XDhNGXQGMm0UcZEOZdzPBGJbQr7/VTtSxjr0p6TU3L054G5hmPaY3aEvB2IwiwGHAE3fdQ5kQwOOyuyjnMJuAY7ipOCoLxg6h@3thcQo7jPJXLiKZ7oZTrK85RArtf@ElYGYtMk7OwxfGOu4jwgv2txGi7qgRHOWVai8rSgT8TDAZuDs5bbEgq0Al0DPxIdFgG4vDBSjykqDo4mHqiY2pqT4IZwjl@vh22wJtj6StbBOv5mbu/1UCU2DhoNzalfRj5iVhHwetZqxbno7qzCsHnftqb0s6BCzGpWYgmhtlJwtdU9t8iMAurPFgfAGdZ6nRK3cIhl2l1TgodeKQNeHdpkQtBNecvX8dsbzh4CAU6TLfc7Zf/YMpTCl@XYHvYzQe0TimcGbQ9kg0EhKQYAM9tymgULQWzKohLgVKT67A3ohGbCSgr7Dkl3XRDDDxBqB1PysAa0uXUxB7CADKJt8ACZdOxTQeSHxyzUm5ti1c7QVu0DlPGz3bj@F95s22u@BQtSP8JNQMRl4A7cFfYKL@kh8oPAk@G4zeSDaWyROCo@CN9rdov1s@6jCrMKWjasgG0ptpGhhdR0UPD7WudjEQ/B4vHwLHANZHF@7sQOTDgp5kyZ59mAV@AHIdLXf6w@WZlPDkyACsn6Ez4G4uKN0ZwXLDZrwty98b7J6yG0nmHSY1VkMdHI4zmI2dXEYScKbCgz4o04fTougP@H88ian2DvM7@twiWw2Vl10OdOP1yPEJSrGwjwSqd2VnREepcvu5Vh7fFNgB@7tBbLiBujqW06t15lf5zDFLa@EKOehg0AfhghQNptrcOjjgmBU4xPIKa1DsfCClTGYvO2/co56Ux4BRZegzFme@vSQiHbyfYOtsCqNi/GBoy4zceCTsBArBYNUTLDo6jQEiDK6ylw@5OXjyOOEQpmd1jlWZ2pV4SieNkajAVGrG1eW1TiYWEA3@XgItHC5qRnOcRsWy8GS1hOalAeFiMGLcFBuyU2cdQDk0o@1920uRj7hcK9sO0e8DvbjoM0ZqmM0Mvnm4h6PSXgm1l0IiZ50tn9zjOBHtk28J2o4AldLgeS8rENtXoSB@7Ts0OiIPiRDA378VDhePuxUBechrGxA3pIHJye47Ls62AF2tdLyU34K70moFCQIAzPbErCyRuQ/WtyxQPhoq9n5l2YyrAYkL7T57557QgDv7cbQZ292bZLQKAfSdz08AWb1rt5Esgw7oDSnXjG5BrdiSj2@4U1R62CYI0ahQDGdgGP6uR4dSiPOE@Ec3kdf3LSgmX1MKAWHRRBtYUKk4J5bCeEgWSPw3Eq8XH2l7cQZS0oFo9WAvBkTrkdD4waBtACe9rbgxLx4Osk2paqJSdKH8RTe0FCZAzbvyMEwDwYfDPZ2r9QaTzcg@wrTg1Nz7Yqjnu7Tvb4p@updjXIlIatGpZFvP39jmly4HJ62p@ZRMhV9TwDm7Hw5o@XELBiMONDmCZAvHYvtxS@@ezorH5xmBAfYCnZA0eYJGieUNE9SmxYG7DvDIdzwnJat48Qz7d4DkazF9DsWnKo9IkeSQCcFGTp65EfJoadObpmtAffcDo2FA8Tg@d7asp3eA5rxbOatE4ws1AzdDENLBP4mN@xaRKM5yAJwrD6fqsBnSeF7XmM5vlyVm/YUGsE1izE9xY9T4dFQH9CDDyuDQeB0C3P4/mIkv3AQXWHwt1fWznWhIcRN6MJYwuAaZna7OfFHobD@J4b@Dpd67kvS0h0@AU5379sPRJYmbm/wVsbRnTfgOlisR2BhYBBEwFbHvtxFxirAEJEWFL3hANAiijLWpriiuatFqTbpmcIV/JwCWzQKWCVwzHONU@MJA6wlx7nAoaHxxiNFaCeNDPrU36B@W/sR6Cuzq16JIfZWnvI0S7RWReH5FTEWHKztW47rz9xEuJIAI8RUY4cOWaFg5ZHdY0asXvn@WaWDfrpO1dNkMPtCfOeUbCBXLtLv2MigYkSjA0IxY/Igo9HNlqhAECpZ1rh1DvYK1DsSdu7W9j9UsA/f10Zhq/g/yoWJxBMKNisaUAvnjighPJN42PD5YufHQiU5yQV40Kz4ovF2fBpfwHEFA2RJWEZ@IQFnG8IjTW4uOB0ROwaHT1fth4boEF/k5AeeTNhzs588V4/q8RRcoFvPs7eR8iTLbsfRC/TGKJwR3CwDTDCrI72cF@PdMRlue2yvyfg35A2bQTuujp0w3OurNDbFG3Pi40z3Y5seJhrO8w8h7kzW3SRF6V4bEQjOBe8oTqjRljBZq4kesm7XD8oCxQAj/E0K9vOAb21JQ@yjAmUDuxpe8xXd7obLb@tRto4f2x1MPH6vp4cth2zkkbe1xewu354pgY8KPZUbUc7Tmre/dnZDN0DnnoiqgERUGUnsJ1MQnPpms/xOIze7bhb08HB79BGCKwj0lB7p26e/IWbanLcXp2vAfORukD3ct7mLl61FyEaVWrewImCCasGVp/myChw61iIJWzowQPxsnHhJFADVlujB4eY4XtsEQrOr/sAT@EvRIgHo0IKvt4bD2C8zlNVKKjjyRJOM@VT0pjmWwSex@Hj7MAQbObFa9hLDxv0TOKBD4P9XwMFrwe0OXCz3m17X0PvhmqdvDdH@rnlgyiw9Yyg8My9ELuv2cTmeUHijHPbvL31MtQHUhA2wLq7h9d8MVEMIG42MHnQEtZf4JqYr6VYDWp5bNu7DlZoRFtfV@18vry/R98gwBaaNXteL3D9VD7CerUF@dZdPEdmO3clnwRVHQkAP8zAeyYEwWl5zmxycNPGxWgrdosefNYrGhgXrc5bI6kyhjlYGXPPfK@ZFo0p9Rs3bDM5EPLuAHCVbIw4DriiyzygdWJ2MAi4mPPL21HAYrPoQEi85zi1cDyUoopH1p488wgEyaY2PvqupXnapz15mIYHSlhrArYJB6g501VotdQlAax1t7ukSL6csYqmZoKzTh4r4GHZGwaHYoWZfjx7fYcVo1xwVqJBf5ALlsd568aHZPjJlT3X1mPPCtO2@zNNTOC4SVLmCME3wVlRLiwJVpURw8spo5rYJQ/kXXdbtQG2QLXpicl42eJD0GN7jVlPXDdLtRvsptc1yncyKFCRkSLShvndzj4@wplnIiO6nD@COPfvIF3PcPAUmUDUg1bZWWk/r9cu9i8kYqaSI742HMIhPcOjdYc6oUdmiAvMFTsMnu/Ii/Bb@DjQzCu8Zg@JV3wMptqXs4CefbaROZcYvoqnJposufbuAgHEK@hZ8uQcVjV7ZoyjSSBuhovwsnd/JeSe3Gr20sl3dCMEzAzuqY5ZQzwRGOw0MDB7C4ZO2xBhmtA9u8TtO8NrlykxRfP2WFRMDKexS@cbawtIg/M43mGjtmdXI9eTtV4b/7cDnyyXh3R/JzR7yJKtiWIj5GR93fgSGCzjem6Z86meNPuZUYXKPs/5DtFNyX7PbzR@924/7tfjxL3hsh5lIfL24ZQV7M9sLZQPzI4eNQQrdvrneMB38WQ4SKkzaMF5YftkPOd1fiWn1Alu3aPLcTFCF6waBErciKBr51zw2BsvYL@Khy3ZxjCbU2cbz7XvxePG4TPD@UszWUKwjYiYnEddOeDI/iQbf6P9Sztvyz/j55ErfMhTgIlfQDw8jugOtwRPHrSFyiOgKBR1a8I@n@dxoPc6rmArk4dtdo9uN3MNM8AkJirQMQp75psJRnYGEABHE9Tjtbd8mOz23DdMfAFSdtRY3PqOESK6bOdnk7mz@SlJk8dT1QA4Ot3nsadC2juaWXFrBxAEWFhwqNmqruOPJjpvsVDbCZe6MGHzfl00PgpeTZA@12M0AZgjkQWmePguYORai1y/OEc6HGjw@L382AjxEbC5LAdCFMystSqJ6eZPgHa2dOIWaaCC0NdFvh2JD3MgjKbHXK/giTWehQeTTB4JZmOOLbo80RtFSvBg1sdOWY/Bhz9Iya6HWffoCTsIeA9EuYQQFMe2p8KjLlMecn2nKI91K8E5Wau3h/z1FHQEAfBJ@AWE2wSp8DL7jY4tW9MTCDHHkjEj5zKhr54fz6daHcTvoLCw128AcB6Y0Y/tYCyeZ@ZoPQMsmrbIoVhZl4oBJ4/5ehDLnk5qVh@ecGUMpzki8XxlJgAFouN0rhOwGVMIX2c5lMeTnZ@WvrMPs6fKvc4aAHDwV3PAJl8bARWSbzbKUwa/yvk1R/V2/7sM05NOQdfhaTkpekLHozgndKOBv9Ggeb/jByeRAwltlpO3G5645vjP4IkxOgxIrZADf4qQ0hCcOxGC0YLFcZraVGMe@JKdAXrfb0Tp9TBwntNmZJTK8jzq5FnaoFD8Up4WbzMKjB96tlewT8WWY7SAhP1Pc/zyL3/5z2T8z38x49c//vpX//bvv//Dr/fH3/7NL3/zj@GXH/O/fj2//MOPf93ll//413/68fO7v/vD7/7wtz/@@u/@c/34zfrfy/w93/n5ub9c7u//ao1f//Lln/4b)

Comment: I think this is using LZMA, right? As a side note, I did a similar test with [paq8l](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/paq.html#paq8) which is compressing the uppercase letter string to 11877 bytes.

Comment: Yes, it's LZMA. Brotli does better, but not as good as paq8l.

Answer (score 8):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>27747</s> <s>27081</s> <s>19701</s> 19229 bytes

Take that, Bubblegum!

```
O("alan argin asparagin aspart cystein glutam glutamin glyc histid isoleuc leuc lys methion phenylalan prol ser threon tryptoph tyros val"^sA*Y"..."R^(PA3,68)."xyz{|}~
 !"Y"uttscfkmovgsmmoshiwnqtwjgioettdwnmvmfisgnjdgkrvik nrdrerjikomezastkvktssdewmdogtvtwweidsrineogsiwedkngwfotnsdtnomowrmsqemikiksoidiorntgkmtniwswowirrwt"<>2)J"yl""ine"
```

where `"..."` is a very long string. Here's the [full code as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/dloscutoff/69d34a4b7f3a54891f61a264b48b74f3).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#XbzZetu4trV9rqsQK6nEcdw7cRe3cdzbsiw36i1ZQkMABEACECFZza3vb0LOWnv//0E5lScRSQBjjvkOgMr/3C/885a8qeKboQx@2vTNvP33/1yxP7IOw29pMnBv8u8v89@P@sWYWcdQkVmd4EG/@PFjZIsSu5hpVUxjrEbJ/PKp0UnRYlN0scHwR86MUqfTuOhGRtti/pb882pPFuv/pOv8wC1zs21v/eTN1TOGkrbITItNB6/v3Lfd6b5YaWf2HV@NpEGRRsQKnNtGnbwJXj/tKzXrO1Qk2Qretql75G/8cfsx@mKI8bMsx@99yc@fM94@ElTlVm32UX6/cJbblzqxXuD5JVa6jLWuqlU5dYi3mcXc4Y7WHZRk9MLKeiG9fEdPnO8n1SKWxeEitjBbVqIrxNUF59ZYc5KEn4/J44ELv9qpQRftz@bEPlqjVIqrvOR8Xdz7ohnooz@@ZCv99G595E75iWMMDxiMS/gjHrUFekKoNC2VctTfqAvUm3G6s4g26rdog6YXj8z4NipweFa8vr6RSG7QEX/s9aswP7ce7WjUO2pY7Hpy7PQRT5MoYfyk51g1a@nbNjx178jhNmNjrbnm0RGSac/hqm/pS183esY4VVMs7gR8/o6vjI90isPla05u1OeflmV359I6PuKSR8mxp/5Y9z8ekIcHvDMimTCbI87XJ/mfHoa7@n6RH6KKSeA@aGbwJT@ouKS5TrkWadK2vFl1dOQYVj7xVB9iVzLJ8lS3W1WW/GElid6QrG/3avVzxPV4cXbgZqbi8GPfOLPPM5Oha3Od68pTYdbzYjo@c48wsRlbSsTdVcTcReugIE1UdGoqGiTyna6NJnHS/gML5qJBfkdz3jmXNOPjjNsvFyqVdyjrLwi8HFv0wp7c9HOcqw0@ZSxjvXUUMZ2tM7aWFSymt6m7tiPG@JPpGnSQZ@PhLdeqIN5uMxFzLwQxw8TnA70oWiP3B@d6mhPNXTfWyrdTl@1Q1L2R/pHopPu5VFITtrMH0lnkR6nKueMRyvzRve@6A5H5vLLX2@txpE60TtGDu310eYEeZTCRGYx6s9fJsWyuTxhc5p0xnW7QNqugghUZLTcJ/OFEpCLKklin9o/Z1xINcv2@1ky6OOcpzbbfcaksza26X/1yg7ISaQqCZGyPVV6A8Slx4H4YNzFTfGJrBtspFMVJas3F/@8/gfGEuVXLJ1jlQ58tDaeZjicCkRhntHErDtN7lw2y5J1z@UJvEn0re@@O203Zqpst2/10izjBT/i8fTkqoELCZybNCrpBXmTvDU9S/ViHqSWGSj9okK1vreSr0SedM91FqCHp6ZQvoMFNHUmin/C1w7F@KRSy/v091pvS4LMco55E6H5iVFLOxREfMBbMgvY058Ms01qPbLmBs13wAxbjkWlT41JfGKjkfThBiOByKn9mf2L7DBWMcosXvoxjXCdfz2jyub45W11UBWa5uhdYi23cYROcooQJNBKRoxzuM6RyKb83j37SdRevMY7@GG70yyBXRHB1srj2@pi/yyR/lp7Gi/l1dxb9ey98J9GzieT8jr5aX8bo3uD7LPEJM8fbGVvRnh76a8dcz88auI/HCdMtxiqsbHW2hsF2/uyhMSqAWegHZveYKlcfmFLJpx4ImWmNVJ8dj6Vx2ZDqTs3YlB1omTEsueXOC/5GUfL6eCuG9P47yIeIWQdvYZkP8sE9Jf67usQ06i@UZDqD@Zeo684TlIHjXnE1Xj7apreo9wBGkrHvrmKy2SxoMGUwAkG/4jTZwtonWU2O5PVWn@Y2Xiqsktn61WZBbBSyGdumnRbYjO1OYjm9J53jQZ4QCgMixzdji7HAnIxmNOpR3s1tdvmuqy7WjXR4KJHcFjXwHv9dULkymU0ntiD8INXvRytmC/tEXlLNbZIq1aGp69EnkttlaEJK1D4LPPW5BdsbmwZ98SC2jUmspy0a2VlYtFUuh5TiFSRnZ5pjdUmwS0qru7nehKZTcCQmtYJuyhNRpqMYVoiT24wVaon9QpcGJHvoyeH519CBjmWuR0skTR9Wj2@yHHVJ@vl45J8Eag9HFBahb482YPo8ImZBdwfld53sjwg5qdj3ZA1vSlTXz1R2b3Lt67ZqrxoFNGtWG2QEjsjpxnJhlBgyEyuDJhG3E/vzK2rPzmRuwSRiJP2q9bl4VQIrUbpQScHNZHP4EKEJqXuUsek0uW7NoHoXC3K4BWigpiysmVbpNmmbLXA0dCs4TM6VygpOJeNqqgksmquW4KmnSUZaNoW6FYVOWtGZlrf8WCV8U6bEnbKF/k3mY0Eon9ZHkZHp2KYNKkmfPbhxxqKXPdHO9fzjzVOqY55iB@WaWEVOCChHULQDV3jS9dM6@NZF0nnVSZM2/USvoTQ8ADN0vDJIH@jR9pjipuS9rx5GsWlOcbr1pG9unwSZuvDwAtPHE9vsrfgOLCnIj70wSj1UQBBtR5KM@yOcfPUFjGWC06zNHOZhBuABMMHnkcpf0H2RLx1tm2jFiuFFFqO0LQ6h1NuDvMe4qjkB5qgzcJajGwXKQ9k9RRs3368IBW@pfy7VCi3mp4YepcbnRSTHZvs6qghuLjIe4@kZbUwHuX3QWg4tzl5TxzN2nfOJDOCzegbPggjZEHx6ikhtgu6tVAnDnaNOytJedm6zWh/sTyW2v13T8qebqBqzcCvjdEYrvbNdmcnelOy0U0F9vRZdfjFDLfkgy4hYGhm7k@vMZ@@UJmDgallPVrs3cVoKj1@F7oHyhiRWd0XyAKpnduPKTrQSu3ExyVRPDU9ixMU@Ao@5ue2aA2jLWQ@apIo/@/zmWwI@/3aWQZsw/G5BqB@x/jdV3dMYAcUtTa6hTq8NSO30Ht3TzHBnGruogJ4rR7Keza5lAyE1ZoxwXttL5BX6WbN8Xwl0tG3lhFM9uj@9y1QsyZtMMm5UD8iAbG/LFcurme19Uek9u3d8o3bNwAaNRantcBjPqGAaTqn@vSC54eedYprYfGR9n/ma6lWn1@SO42hbHyFu0WaNW9UXScFuW0N92uYve0a1KokFIxDHUnUs1PKEPEHfeuywY1vOjEITpvmS6rFki9ymRcplx@o741FT@6MVkKaq9ayqfbln4DakIbmMMdpGG6jCjVBZZVAmHV0ooJfxkcGJTOM0V5G9shFj0bcOqNjwFJFGysoUqRh922OSylF/F5yeC1S16oilC5l947pgxuy@YL@qNvSPaZ6RFYtn@XPdRFr40sZ0VfNVq4YV1mPnFXvGmK/P5FFfiM3eu0ll4ozy19PQYqVPRp/HBPWgz2WMaNXaAqDS8TblxN0osN8Xx2gCzu2/I0UWRLVur0Z@htGBb2LdMRMPZpyoq@Xv0I8OyGMGMtRPd3JvS8f25Pxr204AVPktjUGDuvQzf5vGDnykJbpaP2ql7vGQmR67bUD3XLuHlmdgeFpP9GyIWqxYHBZYoeUifYe1vIcKaDE5RNLsQ6MdDll/5ppFU4A/MBIdRK1bYOCrgx5DaKh3m6KlqyCfTh9jXTZvcMvi6sFyzhuo1YDO1aTfRqyS@TcbxB6rqTlFYxfajyXyzkKCwplE7w@Qn5JvdKUW2DD2ZSVIr3p6pXyB7T9mMzeB9fMzKH@V174r0gMOHWD9rqUvDAWWLXEpIHygkSR055o@uZuoQMAAJvF5PPMF6M4DNTMnlCczo8/gSVBMJdCkIU2Yyj@r0vQNoVUmy@8kUXmjSVB6T2U/R4XOMc7N1Uh17wpKDTs0kns9W8pov812pBF8oBtdVQ5o/b3ZF8c4GymglWeOuks5YCuB0SI5mrHOcwYzQqMWw5hfwFT40R0ilwOrd6lsnlOwnW/oXetEQhdd4BldFf6mXziu2guVReKkkQFkTqATzlgXEqT/XgPKSZNbeH5Cr1TyGbuldkVUEz1Je9EzbfMm4jNWO0W84Sc7Jl@eqYRWUeGBjRvfpw@hm2kgZtmy5qttovcylo2m3mlQDUKMaXxGqxBDo8KF6hSGKhcFnwGTBzbs1KCb@GQ@dliSUcnQ77Izf/ZNlZCYK5G67jTjwIxXFn40Zmx/MxubGp35jD2wq9CR7kz1ddA4OxoLIIiMqea704lNfRM@kbHVqxz6Vp/q5PPxZicMfwQIEqFez0IvryWUnMzmQwcfSNYBy1O@CoO34@yhJum15ScFlIrUVqCSJoLC8I@36Y2A0V9uf2/rnYP58AE/rCYbTfeu19LNhkaNLSn4zcfo7fFzh9411SMAsy34FHzcwcI51oZ@KBNEwtIjte3C8HvsWEI7XoLh42fuhPB0Pv7ZOUrKIQUKEAkMIEJh9ej32h6VpjDIG8d6Yra0b@HKsU/cqExnE6iBlRF6yKpwDwU1VCwsD8PKF5iob0xg5sjVfOxnTDas1nvSo3cMdX6Z0Njd06aDAYSP25gocltMClnZjOj2I@ul8Pzfa38//95v6uOvVLa1QI9BdTpWz6v93H5/dBefRQoTx9jGsiYKkc6Uueum8t@nQ9G/BBAQq0x2nMB7cgSJfg0@zglKJoEeYQb2zzFM6Qz4VqF@1h5yMpGTru4D5Nh2z2ZmZbBGaXViAX/pJch@bcnPaH2bpmf5beoFukAIJSMgkLL0rcY1hqx@dJuR7@CU4upq8PqTQRHTc/1Dbj8of1M@ATx5phzB3acjkuAumQXhbRYYo2UJbYt2XMr0YpQNIBdB64ganzTpslZGCZ7m2NOvOklHTRqLzKx2f0RPnC76vtrsHDiWFZIw/RHLKN3IbMxrd1AZAMCYiDvZO/6qMwZ@BjC0CRfAz6vfcxSLAsWLGGq3wGCh5UmRUzk5EDu3meor8qALK9CrSHq7IkDjPE0roB@8LcGXhjhQfLDFh97F1UQhdKCbbodTdUu9GI5S38opyo3u94Eafpqaq8pr1@efX@XkSsPlBGRu6bchXx/3RSZJ45K2dh/JBEg4e2dThSD5mdFv/e1PYDjaxNXBUp3ivv2@HIltLUQhV6/TC4L9WdcUHCWmcGG/0tYvmLYxfcGZmI4GrMjyd9Efk9x3ylAsJ4NrlLrHPq3VI@oL4ii3r48h0UoBD21RHWKP3zGdQ1t8GZ3DdPLzlQZcpfHbSPVHdvB3Jh7I4CQmKXRINsp1JCZakK8qx9N/9dOUmopUu6MdirIC5FJaQyDhyWWLmLFUrdM/5tDVBzGgsPYTJyiepdUayvvKt00Fb@kvN40JwTPX7kr6cnlh7EGvAX95/GChPcNzUPrbjGBC9N0UVz9pn9IsopPlFlUroperTPv4Aipkt2tQ7lfNS3pq6i1aZKADTLFDxMpsNKBFTX7j5h9ZwLHBb1QPPIq7xvedThkMiEFyQzk8hiKYi9LQHgJdSL5xfYTuZfY8U@ppNHtyurNfjwQ0bT3@pHdS2eB0bdwhLa1PI@kX1uz12Y8OeoHIgOsbhRf/PPwFpknHNPppYzUakCKmv3VYG1jgOq34QaJrp7Nrkum63jSk9@PVo3/TXKCuWSmZ8VUODaf4y2HwovEDikaD7yZMyPjPoICfzTWM4zEmOjWzawdPL0ZE66/4delf9WRgcfUpg0VsUiNpcVAUQzcDoVbtoyKfhix5F1cdCypJG@5sdfDo@6K1zhO1Dx2b/ZXJi0bdiqmYLbMU32mVF20RDyaXZKyJ22l8ajENz0J@FNboI9ZiAHHw2s2udewiM2JvKvdhOAise@uGdRaWoLNn6@ZXjhS6pdFa4mlQmibv4lByDI@ie1id4cHsqfpkaExeQbGdM7aS8cf@zycvEngUx2StQ81neJRnlUT0CUN7QxINdJFpIt7Mtz9JIY2NP2N6kOIXe9ikjUyDR/sW7eW@DKOCJ4LgVWkzcose4EZDJ@nEJfSb73R1TZrWK2q13BQW5703K1E8gsxIkzb4aGvxcedJ3owngItv9ZIks0uxvxs/NEt0rM9jPa@/7P0Mpj3J/QTfPWHsfhif2i7RtU8zCovczbPXGUytF6KbdxrEXCJOjeZFWvS04CFkuD6U7BhGpPLfWqZQhVpedRkerMU/E9WSo5srkCzIn78@/oue2sxYXC86vRFW@kBflj9PZlisSvRcar8ZyE7jQXOVXLYYa66hA/UISNj1R2A2md8fcQyNGTKR7lpeflwoG5oIlafNAgz5y9VB7Kb@2ZlfkC@BEehJ1S7FGkb5/Jt9IzcT/VAd0spA@ui0nMRfbaRVJ9QlPBjOdn/F06HyMMfZL3pAh7JAI0tsqmaDn@aBvAWHGUz03ctpMrD4ZVEBljUQ8e9qIkZBPDGMzhxntrhlqiihpl38JQ2Ors/XOxN4BgShT3Sl/5N5CiHNnxEN14EYo9PmI7@ZMXknIBCWp7DkqPur67iJfN8cFVHheToTX7hMn6plaTYicdhy2n/qse7zA76F@fBnugJdA5UfErBtP64TG7/pDKEL4C2wbf@shj4iWKcxPPVg657@ZmMw9Q5@uEoTN8DcdBzDVsd0LGA4R7l@vbwiOhPxr4LclQrWSv36fI9HNwxzfDp@HvQMtkHAksOCr@GEDmnG8Muais26zVSBPDNoSHtBO0xCWdp9oAjJ6aovuma59iiumzPwDZ9IsxOJ/dToDlDsT@c7Q0fR9rjHpriCqgwErtEjo/rsJioRrN78K/FJwecUegAGqohos2/jHFzz4BkeiI2T/JKu0RLWug8tKiIOFdbyL4PgWILvBZ/4Ktqrsd7S4XlMjvd/iaFeunD6LVXTT8VwleBZsNQM9AhrNMUHYyiAhihkpIVhfmagZZQiSdCT/AWGc@@fQMxZ8ZeN72dAvOdtJaAgrn6bYOLpETtzdLD2AsCr1dh9j32LqF4ZvC/MTjAte@260tSpPGL3PoM0KaDKYuVjjd74Cax5Uxw6o88HUK76SiNIPj6h8p4iPnH/nl9@u4/XbOKOczuGZXvi1bBhPIP20/r10JjSMX6LcW0A1kvpO3S15h/fWXPyXaNP@gUs5W09A79RNcY5lHsohi@/Cg5cbv0CxpVDrTcbUqhgpD6B64T@ZKLkRyEGDKDGnekeAhHFZI0W2PZygaqC6M7XHj1Nh7budwGG@SFNi1ZS1ctSVmBn5EX6K0h@mXEjAElU1ENKemYpv05eNFDKdezUpeEWY3st1M0YvRB1VuqlwF1L4vCX321mzE53eOpqg6z48NGpOhryEKCIT6YV04vdDcgHFixhUKAyBZL4@qVrniv37gKg2LYE1Lmb2ghDnbsXkMt9DgODtU8f1u0aLBmmpgn2psQ0oITqvFFYep/Pl97vlva3TD1MESr@yoyO6Cd9vjMZWOARHcHK5z3wPTZgWjz0Hs@08nCJnkAZlBdUuXySXdMNXSN9wJBp6fZz6ZFieZs8iUv8DeXT42I4ayHpT@z2j@qdddQ@h2gD2QjbhAufW6WufqIu1tVvnvpnKPQzkymUkBF0cLD3zN6H/vsxL1sYo08muokwJ/UVscmPESy2RP9aKdLdrOAqSF3emTFky3s6mbEIVjsKFPA1mCf0B4s3oU1liY4IJaqG9c0sDOd6D9gKRuMFhy6exW44jh8A2YtOJc@vVI9OfBdlaBSOIsVwqKeD7IHt@AkEtnCiZeoKTXTzCm/Z4zy@LZDTN@jOWcxfbmliYJmn2Wr0kKe@Dbp7Dqv8AzqvFw9@kJrIllDYpJ6GRX748SqTfyFktsGtpgupRg/4tQVWzo2MWPRgkYLJHAJKDOEiUN4uhTW@iB6MTMyNhr8KF4nBIqb9n/ILxD1btEOfQUOQaAjAeY@AkGNiPR0NeBEn0O1UWGQO3rDKBjC9JHH3YAHuK2il/M4drPPS3M23DEpazCzNKJ4U2eYzIim640nTi@tyDcl5FehooHsU0wOnLySNjH/TkxMCCYa9f8ntqEAMeqtOZ0uB0zCdTNnJw9z3eub5t/9LadSXEB9YU6tDi1xMsqtE/RSEQ4cDtOG5wGGdzbCJniGOFn89qASwxtMq8LyHqaE40Joq5OBYnA6aWTUikxhUu81FNQe7@hdWWYn9aydNJz4CQRdtAXizI5SfPa0/ZgbJEwE0cjVYf6803WpyE8g/O/cjUG0ZX3dzPp7CmN6qfgOS2XPrl9uVRD5H90nq2jCrD7/NJSCa5tf4wQ2En9o3W9UNaRKIFN@hiB//1ZAFfj2fGuevEg3d1gIr@oiOGUH16af9xTCEPGX4LjoePL5UjdxpvELd7Qni9l59BrRZG1pzHgo7PmxCjyZGN@jindtR/tOwNk8SvhDz4RlMJSQPAmI@4TF6bUH9i58wDU0IhdJ3u@ZO9e0legB8KrLCcxTD/I8foQ7ciVQXM4HvDR1/6h0vPbI1Tzc53ceFbdlDjzvJ8Y/2FTkXCeJvSAJ6H@7GnDQiEvVIDBPBiPloZiQDgeEh4QCsVvoSgKhqQqCHNP0zzwNzgPj8rus4GKgCWwKmOuzeE5XIHS2qmc8bA3xIwdVILU9AIY03SgcM@0S/yZ5LoK4ojguEy73XFad/iu7WYAZp4nbG6PbQPzdqwkOWuD6ZPD2KYXbv0aeHhzodYWvwTF7jnXNYgpG@wvb9OPdRHbrtW@ZRXg9xAuJiQ3o63QLK8THEGgbd57vkofi@u7XUD05zaA4jc@YiHOb2x3x5z345ZoeXqPqVDsUhfCrS0x5L3S14EcTFYzv@k010TyeneNB6WUTyHuNUrxC1T8Hn@esslG8XiMMeBmLuQCQhr7fXYWNoDH0Z1AKZ8yDk1vRQy52SWRXAqqBKxNVjbzmyz4wcgVRiaBfcfxGHfdVDctiTULqSPpdSrNXl41NsTlSG5KM4PIDSxdp/ARB71IJ7qvx1ijLoXuQU0wXoyiP1YlBXb2Qvj4FPd6cUunJUtXEyHSCIf7956Kb6bgda12l0P6vaLImIaomwyBFAQr4rWo62hkslasLGWRHrSR3mRBML/jlQxTIEJPn@o53fMcbNDv7EcutntPbRc46/anCAC7Ihpvt3feH3UI8rVQQDS@/5uPmkdbmDEp@LYWLATgfA16s@Ok/URqJ3zq0EuIzwg/0DI/n3/Oya6@YtwMXBL17MaJtKuoNiWxsAy01@kxCxACSnWNBBhFQpDBP7400jjn7M2UJABBhZo1OPwosIolUxmlxE@uUhlqCdAT1c@A3BSHVwD/qyUoMZItfq8ZTlJn4CsphA2pMQywjAUbBox/LoIjWeghGwSxrp0@nm4MLoJGxOZAUU633xkT3dQcKlOWI3dUgkGvGAcfLCoZd2McTGSKp/fRFLWvMoXVQhQxMfP9d9JoapgYil9btTatgXzRSlHOgzdhPAiBeYGkFvxv@evy3Wm41g0KWZhKSbb2GU1oD9J8Db5Adw/93nQzJAfFpvjW1sCyF/zDUr43@/Cg89xy8zMNErYnIYDo4hZbXJ@AHcEe5e3Jnbc@hcHL0AuuEhILxr1IU6OmN7IJRwbA9ZequkEcoBTHheRBA8jPb5tcPn0xqoH@Xz2S3M8M4WCbOyz8l2FWcsCln6mn8AzouWf7bMVovqJDcPcrPIugndKVc3y08RIFjeAnsrGj0e2CF5KQO1iOfmKc2us/J38vKVPukfowmkkOPejfSzv5ksmrE2dOE8ghn5Bg9B8lu@Rvt4ETTvWGyr9rVFJuzYApf4rP8zD0246zBFsxKHqrmljUc7heQKxDLQw8T@xt/@3NJsxBhkKY59uljbzi16GAF23YQ2TrpnpjK@vaD09oA@N8Q@VXGuUI9Y8gpNpSmGBzYsaxeIoX6Np4Vz9LK@CeEi5jocaI4bxD@53lm7eSuGX4wD5lyNQt5tQNk@zBd1srbwAneP4tIGr7pXMLKEiZTB7cOKdkWjYqS/SAzkMIqKRWgc9DFZmI4@QYquzpNGMsn@Cn0Nkao5STHNACBgEBNwoRAz1FPY/dqvmFto3PJD52QMn4k2PzHz9V0kegQkskb37eIAuIckLy0Wo@UogPjx3uvJFXFPqH1QOWXuG8DZ3oGT/tm45vuo@XQtlwhqSyWG@xAwrH56ODFbYz6GDnuejpp5HT@g7g1kSpOd6UIyi0Lb3i20ybSv66NPoG3TtAGnPmOlPvkpo5JDxSe@rjd58HSAwyQ/7pqVipmFdpP9@sWGbEoCYNZh9g99iKN/oDvd6cXy4BE1nZnSchyA@@gNmvb0XxxyVmlhKX0AXUPMIiaJwNAXS@B94Fng55Mx@HkyRzE0aF67M1Qe85Bqtl3vK3ltwyzSJ9816NLQgizcpQeQV5/7ZeyUf3yqncisBRkL3UefHogkDQIw1yHQh5bVpryPCc6vjzOfug4xT3pR/MfHl0jZuLD9F6lkQPc3f@O5@93V8WJ@Wnc6TnTsQnKoMaAXUHUaVN01jq0zM0OVA1tcUESmdAymBWMxw@BaMJQO4li/Uf4pGbuZAAZ7JCPWZTcZB0G82CdsD@7s4eWMcZeq@@fyF6BQdXn1REmzIA3koyEEB60F5bLBHccvGVuvn0q418/4ccvu5mZ0ERgGLMePJQ9h0vyay3u6lUWZDc2avItWO3Blirmjp25QUHV3iddzXccjBzYMrTbszeYAIGJs0UB6RHKT6davM8MjBMQdoC5h5gOqYIFB51/UgLupRtDciMz0uRi9S7T3evlv@rQ4tMOKSdV/RN5SIPLERVBsQ3YjRKbHNmzf7ROBBw1EMkvk5OfyFEqFonCNK0hlaO7laAwwRgsHuunpLHtwlw3URa@TnWlwLZcy0Pl7b3J2NWnKneyUqJeHU4wXBLoZgc7hTleJzAj41uEvtqsQpIeKjn3Imc@hz9Lkx8pc7@gT8aiyEulGpFUjiD0sT6h7M6kYYH@T/wq7ufeRA5Gkt/FAJGYh5KkfgdYhqeNBMya6OqLlXIeBQDvYg6QaNsoOrPlsICui@Npnw1@CGOyfP@PztkTA6jIPRZMWJFL3bHXAZVR8atTtzRguQo5yfQItMiUVoUDzqnVmdJ/iVBVZ53mnrH10guLYldVc9fR@NrigSdc@61LHluyN2vSCvOBs4fgH5A7oauiv4H9x2oBkWLVR2KVW6rduzvV@ijXKT32dxEnVDrSnXB2J2AK8LM1tfL/v@hb0fqiKx2OV0hC4oRmBDSS/8TxFpdzpsNNdj@uziNXHkE@7gDBgHvynDokO81oLWFtdQj/TSmXELS@hLm142spk2B1B0SB5IK0GX8cv/VNGwFFHTYriO@pFkvvZiFjQQMcpchk6tNudpavRjh3XBr@@/raShJ3h69N1mMlp3V@sQzrADQdVy0NGxvnxaa5IBVIHYMNfjfuoZvFCylYGP037N74EJ58jiwRkUeDk0sCgsqoL25@FYGMSaHJo9ZTFuYfuHIcWf4@@hdmItqGjuTwUvyzoXnj9DZy8tEy@XSfz1lygCQaJX4SNh6xiKqcCjS9WAXpwO6Xm64OTtwnq2gwmf0cCyEnjJB80BT2qEXcxCc25bmszih79giA/Gleg3C620ctfld@2RdQHt1Jhc3r7N51LNGjcf7qliKy4GhhyiNk/b8JOyn9FfgusEnz2QIN5ulDz8nbADku/WchRkzXaEyefcJysbXbL5bCFQhIa5gI9AccCviFwLhSHbabhLwJR7JKO8bnPagAWMp/HhTAhMX3x3U9p7IruC6mSDpDTRAM5ESCnOfX4brLT2v1WYHpyAED6PCnrb@Tk6e2vxB1I/Ni/sxMwim80Ol@2yj@DxPOF4xsAlfMzkHg0lzgE/UbEoFqnY8CU/5V4sHS0EYHCgbkHWv6vxKMPiSPudkzT91scNO7pX42HswvgUP4DFH6VVPSgEl/M7PbGmIyCwNXrLdC9FnjLYKtQCyz0QfmOoTODsvPcrkCapI2UtdrB0sef9Pt@EDiw1MLzyNVChHt4F5Dsx@C9t4JXSx0ZPQ/Bc3ZnGaXTftA3KSpwz5hDb1pZu153fkD9XOPgWg13NufPDCQuuM3QZAt4JWg87xnQeFZHwGzpJQ8@/hK2Rv@PzAFBq9@Sa54BSwO4iQ7wSh72CPxxSZPKf1V@dm9kOsM/x9ufIHz9TscfsPL@V@K@4/iHi3P8Xxcfbp3ujtEDK@zPBa5fr6V/QV0HJu4TYBXXGZQF7XWYvfjeJA6QCalNkPeJhPn4US6BvN8WM/Mfea9EIni4HQ1sUHcbHKHw18JvUcVHxDY@1P2xUfhX3vZgKdVB3/u/FicRkSi0NIiy5DCY@HwU2IqT4OFreEyDwGEUwcKDwOEK1tR9ns8FHjzcEZRIfx1i23iOLsHF5/sNMtY7jLHg4@AaohwBkLf1iCXByiGKQtrx4OV12zqb3VM9QffPz5Wy/gLw8nYhIXllOrwcDDx@x7rLVK90tHi54eG0JKaYBCBvTD6sPPrgcU4UmrFHAPJM@UDk0NlmJL@kf@0ckanVAcozXQD4EEiGDQcAmAyCSqvgPGA56hdt8Tga0Sn/XFLpX0NfCtGaGx0Otaz0fat9TDYAgqw4mkND/lMfg@CXRHD0keTGNvbB0HMrebD0jjSX4vCQtAezd2bmhl5grn66lMieIA80O76J6sQ@uTojtUs/Gf7yu49ALjvZbTsctMzF3p77@fr6IEk//Hz8/9H6sT14thpdroCZfwg9su0HnqqVudDfzyA7JhPe0//Hzvn13M2fA5hn@v/aefZ/7Fx6IHMC0KJD1Prw84f/1frEMdA62Dn/j50TsPOt87mdS3pASs/g5pfBzF3mJzsnwcrp7QewMIcuUtY8lRA1FMT7@MQFtTdqxIuzRWnGQe1v97uNaG7mEHWg@LffBSLt5Ecn6L32iU8dWwE95cHO9//LLF@C3HcjFEP01MVfp/dTFJDFRxClPX0/Y50/cu7mj5/0X2KZq10kdm9@cBrkXjHWZzkGuSP1wek6urYQPOFBPvz8YAbimDGEdthgPdi52D7my/AkPaDt/9h5JRRfff/tFh3hzl9kufXlUh3cPGrCJIObM93/MqIY8Q64eaouKYGSWRA4J@DnxL5VP5jFGnvwMpJ3M2D0kMQ3QeUfjL4eRF4fExI7yG0d8l9iKX0QSyD0KXQAWNRI@WDnrt4MCrdzQv8gFlD4aez4zE3qbTFCXTY/Rf6vpXMFEr@gHTm0hf0sccCU6I43JDALlCuvv4T3z7hTPZD49LwaWXD0Uo/6sz0VT4FX3sat8bdgYLsncnUaL4zbH3tgf/Wte@uA5Ymc8o2Lz035OHJvQeA@DgI/zyvn6LYP@rZF0Le@Ter6NFXRgLdePmAl7@FzEDeUAdFyE13z2TSIW6V7OQ4@/iSPY7v43bT@ipvfRwDki9MGrGXIXFdB2/guaLsRkxsij1wOrML@GrnPQN07Nhxen@5@mwGOFyGip3T2Si/9DHV9Q5Id@XS479uDq/dOh@ELx2TbUZI4NQrixtfQ2vxoHsKx9egl1gHdnsxEEjECgdvaQBwevYsdSfM8wRoUnoCjy@/d7fTznFfmUB6J//i5R2Hve7lli58nYxv1wM5VPLD43v5m7fACyR0UPGTQFw2NipZnp6IMye1jPoBY9iufjTrpBzPfD1tPWgJMVd0YiHxmVAbyHoubQq711jUdVMHObPmM3YAynOiDMmY2HKSXKJQ7NVyi3h1j8DHglUqKq5uzp9Jy6lqv4rBFlmCOr2nZYZRDv1jAn0cdgggmgVckJ76GSiP1d2fFkfEKhbFs1Aa0FWLbAfh4AuVe0hoNphFInOAa1HvQ@NzGp93g4l9M3/XEbMyGtsi0EsEB7XQ0UB9Y7kOPRBMtuCaDWbxxdZokfgoTQirzDZp/@VONmjul9v1mj883R6FZZsYmzueP6I0Am0vTDvsKUQ2/txr1FIPLs/G/I0lUz0Y7T3hvjBDQl9Mok0TegtIdkCgdM2aj8LrF1988Ij9U486dbnxiwchdmmqf6pHrBqk35/uJNJELKI5m@zcwG6dmEJHozo69CFY@BWZBt6D29OEDzXmQu4Icm2Q6cu2nzTm0oPkWS3hnYwlJir4XMXkc07ae5xTOgcY@rBxSG@j9U7Dy8J2AZVhbTiz/UPvGW5uYyu3uOJYLudi9pPuTG@ZnOX76PCs/wUwcALXkD7S3DSCgfFwg61SVwksvO1gRK@K9RpmgtFSqn6xIELrY7WRVMPKxUgNc3AkVN98m/oyhH6RTlkxYLMfrWjbne@d/XXzLApNDmze/vtxHeqzD2Sb8/UOJgHv@ZGDielGJQaaXeu7kGvP5XhPZyjmoPA5Htnw3BIyQPHdCEP91dSJ3TvV52Dy3gd9QBPZ3AvgKvLI@dbr7uA6@NyVqKF6CuKBOn3jXdNKfZgU9SGAVAHKPyp8vr6C9r/jNACt4fraJH5gm6o1e5LYDEHcOmQ1SE3jtNUTPDglFq8/ddK5zhGKut2fJFJ9FMCG0uDnfQ/SdNVpfcwPrp4mOzz9nepPWWNVkWQif4STg@3yzpd86OKG19OG0ai8By2n2249ZODXTx10OH0@e2tXvnSlXPW79BNbzCoInCDySu@MZ2xzfe1oDPQvEo0cpEuKTyX6uxXBo24PG@77qVbLHzFYZ0eNak1z1EnF8c/lMNmIsUWvsx@oX@MXuSbba3IEHCJVKwwsh4xiGDkvKHRno1MfnwCoQL4ma0f78lRng8ik3amq/@asE6MX8EsPLnET2PbXhrQdYEMiHWQLd4D8Cf/kMZXeX4zpwhnieb@j@a59q1mwZq5cVmobN8jNDf9Dozo0b0FPKv8HK/tjOGhc/cdgUXqaANfwGoM0ICmb@DdR91i5afi6@pQ6vEl@UhUzc59n7ZtN2bbmJ1AoYF47CS6GFzlpKUjYmS2@fVfZI6xjSq/A3hStServqN2cr1@b4dvdkmYy7Gix4AONQ5D0@GP/FFOAFpDpUf0fc3qDmJgEw50FZOtDn4fOWuUVc8hvInV/ujSVjAUQ9GlwEH5ec/5iAketTPJj5tj4M3y35u6P6cy9LfNhd8bsl0caqGd@Zl@Iv52fAKVU3nQSFg4@nge47aVylStBBol/6KJ45fBPR7dDkw/k9tKAnLRa@R2fNDYpHAOTgGyTT3CUA5aUTlUnItmFnwm3AVRdIrbwjk/WF7HRUCIYcmPwG/hdYZXG8/OHku@PsIcJvdUBpmBD1LgDtP5JKCWM74L7NIKJjLjP9QlVftD7KjeWhUPZSiFm@zsCsihg/315bfb4RDoeGFOw8HBykUOxvVA0KT4nTfLRcwKpQhbAyu4KHySvmDjLnpewZ3jFuZyTGhKtxeAXFLAOxtD8OuvSEpVj1HMXT8foDXh/NFlIsAnhlAF7uaeYyG90Cv@9Gu52phQQaNs6gjN/FGfsgL3vm0ICrl/MZdrwZJaOv6Xyrp0LCW6FDSF3f@gmErqI9cPje58kUgSvak/DGaT4/1RnMxe4CmUO9teJJTObvZxTmu5IuHA6hp6lGldLh/K0P0PsBYGMEFBcOh@xBIPPb0O@HU@bFX4CRU0qy5QjVmLjee10KORTk88ZOd6MYr@aoqPvPFyoRVEUnCObRP6MNMX/B8tsnDVn0WX3X0@2bY1zfaGaQurYsNOsZKZ1pNPXpLMDobnw8muLo6GOjxe4fhbdfk787LWRwWejGxtVyH4E0yV9P34W0NT9EIOErdbb45Z75M9FLvkn@CWj0Xfxsk1yFw6WeLX/CLw/5bX6NG5ENr0bG4YWVKLg6AU/HlmRtkLy9Mb/sAf44FG0DMQ3T/P2MggX4SXr04CgfQDNIHKmfQMNebtFGKvhXO0fbmUgrecXKfscUMEQ1OlE7tFGNTp5KZZVO5zusHnKo5l@guWH07dqFbx2qTXjCF5wH1Xf@5fZ4sb408/k1TImxsxmb4oVoPGBh2woAZr4dp@8QSjGCFuhCEFU5bsMSn6UJQPo9kWEj/bvb2lBT1lKtq8ltOPqLwovJQ5X/xiMYC4r1k2MhevlIDZ2fJA6m5Wc3vBFxMt9ZBDq9cxGKVmjZ7ztJay41vCqT1tNhQV0a@QSjQaVBlqE3XWYVHBUc1I6/gkixfnLdvZk0SHTmKq55Keebik0JIa5uxyGIMijggxr0So4pSg7FYH8KWINPM72MgxfNs0IdRP/lLd@u@E6Mz0/A3pnblhmd4vfUjQZ5kVFgoEAevccdHMi0FYEB5/j044QoweHY7@IN6OUQIpZH6fx9JDEE1ePo2uHP8/DVYqviTUd/VCflYX82YSHGrRun5d3NKNnnAKj4dQni39Nu1/RbZ7OIpZPc0L1nhvOjL9kjF@ISj@aHZpmRsf7UE5y211Aq6xWYE6YueztgBGc5FMaE6PhYb@TNx8s3Q@z97iSnVPJH@zj9AJmdsOkLJt3SCA1u5AJ@PLOAswJiYCFPXqf/csC6YaPCTGSqRkHoKVr44Z8jHU4x7eHDbxz9yTu4506p9o8JqfLxegr9SrXmffMbVD31osY@G1Qxt/GDyejQctOdyBpQbrQdklz8Lnrhrc5CjrkVC2igF0kPN6nmy1IINamzvflBpBO1Q4wdeFDT6ZHtHoiTXvoAqlRdhHgt5hJ60j5tQtFkorfJLf6q0/N3DNMy8qlj7Ch8DyeW9Z@@W3DnWqntuuFZYv4Y1fuai403V1bQl35AA0WpG2QJMLfaJhUyDodQyU2iAHnJCq4mT1/1CqT97MxTJJ8LktMhHbpd6TtINYjdaM@PiQfz94Gge/ZEH5x2alE7cgAiLwB6T/OewYkL4GwmU3srm9ZkbCgOxNCNw7FNfBs2gUvAmyckzycaeiknegDXYEzeOZ/ZGVGdcDw5@06U6FYGlTYzY6O3WpIfJFmPlYkijzm3pB5eYoxEYoYyfNeBi9439N7IsTwCBvwTvrtaiiildZ/zxzrh4m16VpoUWlcy2a@GL91vJKjc9dOmhBgrhjQ4C4dEQjcpISLJ@WWEbdjMzQwRBfzwlOW38VUoKcqrhWe/06JFLGZTWsILL6NPzJTmb5AVdFx3fTwoe8HRHfT1S6IyUbUgnMt/ATFqw/AiuRv3aBWjlOSrzK@6u2nqdCk5dz219zWVfUAD3M2@@ATHYVGreXqVzWZnlC/Neu1w1HaRYCJVohJmM2ZTxmAVZcaytniefy@cfEYZUz/v5DT3Cfff0XamEpsQoMuMntyTbzl3GJ@7puxkgl9w4GtKXpVaRvd5ju7hMwn1U1en6cCqM@XzpdoXYjLVd4Rz2SEyJf2bbJWhrNfugC9knmKlZgwv4tShCtpOzKDBdQcDw19i10gwhhTtVPNBkdRP0UU7FgKdWJjwqb@a@VJH7k4Fl2my0WVCJLMc1rZDcspPeTTIM/HIJ6Si98Z77x5Jlc/oWD@/uxxDbH@heZee532VzcQjg2yd5zGUVKp1E365BqSY4CJb3lc5qULk7ZLHTERjn9ybBC69CPUgw@ip1jcZ29JC5RxSpI0ciKd/c3tBvnYXYn01ilQCwYKelk2arYXXpPrxkQCgjzN2Mv0CfwSpUr9zU1O7pPMtYYDHQAvJybW6v/6T4483mD7HHCXbBVyGJH@ULfZYwnCyormk1XLal7UzZlsj7lEPlRnaUPkQTV111n2ddJjuMazLqcmB7w3YAF/vhN2QJs9a6VaqB3DFE8r3UnP8jG@5Plw7qeEB41nuU7OPx5Tnh3qApdE1TulEPpoLmB5jDc1plufgQtgCkbZXGcRuSWmuULoGVclwecLYRInMlooW22KSsZot5@cGRjIrAABr8pqf5gn0V90vfc77ZRgS4ghBTRrNMccy7d/BZcsmWudJDRi38pyltscWsV7EmN9FbMw6jO21NXzu7vy8hFU5PE7NuLyj0sMpUyf2kJs@26PXDId/9uUeu0Mc/qmXKZBHDYPm7UVGZWbxnk3B@RuOVytY7/kaJOzl5@QAj8sptgluxQIMCmdQRSt26Pqz8E8ViII6OtcyuSGfhR9N5HOcOAr9Bm/EDvCvW6J5/TkSgt64vMQxXmUtbH12P8KOoRy1bKarlZSVzh/ZzHKwZXdna3YvsaV@uojQhC1OmD6FmWquK3QhR0McNvv3uvDMNr5@Z6YFgbUcXvCqfb5IeLT@VZ9mrG1XSquC5Pa2QCrHR/3lkeT6ImIaRbaIZ/behB9oZs1a@I1NDNCggZsPnbnTK8n@FLhyzLNGv9STV6PYF859GfWi8D15HbZFwQygVeQWvbu9BnDRiG3Nv@Xb7oozWyXbGaAZyhZlwvRUQ9TReotXHTuNcBXIFN2bth1eRmL72k23rL/K0KzeNYcOyU9wAzTm4jjXNUa1EFk2kUn1essKdRO7Wdh/nIaviTRR85ohrqdhucaGa41uj1iba1SusGZaubJHWiHVYyW91GZstojqdrIofcLYuGo5qrBHl/SbKDvlqZU/BcfKNxCRT3U6GyzBuo5IheUh575R7kZNXkrw6pdR3K72vsxintNRrVejByhrc4MtJ@ESZGkZZsDY@074EiPZb7ctmbaxxcTndnJCStOF45vmFXkVPLb1kkr9viowY@9uy5/Ftd1@y865XUltSR@VsvMM5AyLzVKdlVILmTM9T49sVkjPz2F62yR1fHL@WaeNp5MvRd1B@1ttuXrsRx7FaLkLQo8GFrwSgzrtERc4S8JuBh25TZlSMI53mNGaEj@zt4X6i0xOrPyn8rpQPtlc2tr5tvLPcPQ@nkxnhWL0T/2fgXO2T4TUObVSahszrzLnOWUaO4e8krkkzFLFERUmZ6KoDDLYcCa0xO9v1olcOGsR9hJp6nLnPWbIGqawppZ5jISinminLHJKS@2NtBmWTDBhNUNMG@WokE4xb732zBjv/tk/3Ph2/c8o@ecfuM4///M//w8) (Results are truncated.)

Strategy: split the name on `yl`, and encode each piece as one of the lowercase letters `d` through `w`. Use their code points (between 100 and 119) to index into the list of pieces (which is of length 20, so the indices are taken mod 20 automatically). Join on `yl`, output, and tack `ine` on the end.

Further compression: find the most common pair of letters in the encoded string, and replace it with an unused ASCII character. Repeat for all ASCII characters `#` through `c`, `xyz{|}~!`, space, and newline. The code takes this twice-compressed string and replaces the characters that aren't `d` through `w` with their corresponding two-character strings. Goto paragraph 1.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP 18731 Bytes

```
echo strtr(bzdecompress(base64_decode("$base64encodedstring")), 
[A=>alanyl,B=>arginyl,C=>aspartyl,D=>asparaginyl,E=>cysteinyl,F=>glutaminyl
,G=>glutamyl,H=>glycyl,I=>histidyl,J=>isoleucyl,K=>leucyl,L=>lysyl
,M=>methionyl,N=>phenyl,O=>prolyl,P=>seryl,Q=>tryptophyl,R=>threonyl
,S=>tyrosyl,T=>valyl,U=>isoleucine]);');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#FJvHjoSMtYRfxfLql1g0OUiWrsiZJqeNRc7Q5PDy18ysRiPEwKFO1Vet5j//96t//19k9fSvdVu25Z/0yYtsGn5Lsa7/pMla4Oh///6SF//82@p/k8EJTODEbhAaNZGStFyVIi3StPn5ALTIMAMAPGZCEIfpIsdSh98nL3Pqu1GIYR7pBBA2hYjUYWxXLh3mvoRH8R68A9T@HvZA1ziZfYHsSGhum5n7pVvmMFUAKbICAEUV41KMyHqnUT/Bdo72PgEj2bwUSPiDbulblsV77LFR5HOD@0O0hLljx4IgQ1iGK7DtQEF@gR24MLcAjh5SSODYyhDCU8KcKaRAMuqCiPdKqIDgHgzJjjLdeoIgivfMyPtjIUebxXBSfGHEASmfSolTpKg9x3KSIlYAgQuKKjMCeW/4/W2n0Ke9BJekW5d3ppZ3abrquumE9IH2QPCeLMMjDYa2FYvzzYul5a6nDRekK9bxJAZQwHi7Pa3dk5AAVZPQIQdEEhchHFCx5@TANEYiPaMZiTaRioqHaQ9eNSr8tbbLyfQtJfq4/L4/3Y3JuSIfYhJT2vSrI9tZwyelD9JUTrryvM7K812h6M1jCwAnLY4gavUNGMi9prriWRoM@VYe5zgH6NjQWwTicUUlOqWEMY3271PnRI@m@VKJgg4WlkKGyIrew0fczuLAE45O@tTAdNFh0Co2BpWHS3H7moPN/iJM2QS/vzUd9uAAKVLN7jxL62IjGyLF/DQ0YF4o6oauCsxRPZ2uJrs1XtPAmeNGWJB5vl54OhXmCd9uzIIRlW2ePzaWwZ7VyY0jiKwfvHNPqUA//hf8kd/9AFNqxuykP3KcZ6RP9nmqAZU/nAMBU44vAy@IniEmpnn84uaRVKZm1Rb1BwlXZFdD6Aq2i40mIbSWvMsem4mS6Vj13CMHf7KnNojJmshwULSnQIMAKGPo3qMui6tTBL4ckFAOmuCgZv3h1vkzqhYONsVYFWucTPLtqfa@mpGKiSfSCTRYuenPZbmOryqZbfoIOX8yFlKQKXkZeSMubvwoUjPbqEXdwlxqcmZTgW/ZAptjDag@GfjpzgNzhnqFreojDRgI3V/KOuBCzL4smluu0f8@QtmdUSs3wlpLii/wA9UbaulnHQqVi6EwbSHltGqDX5/Lth8FQ@knmfJqQj/euPW2TzleToQKKUzxJg9fqjFDWo3ajwA1uoSpO2/K2Hn2nwDpY@8zgmROuVhtH5z2W8zbuuOj5tYZA0Ll@hTDh5NQTNtL64QtByHuqrjyRM3dwDtnld2zza38aLcD8N2Rc2yEMU3k8tcCKhMgAEZ7hxPNqms@dhpXp50TkXd3oUtg0JbtEcgNZRvN/ch7nyEi3SKFAmTwYAj9authKqRNDErS8M9mdPcYhScPn6TRwLRa5IVkosR4boB7qCmN7OihALGoyvWWcqn6@6r5h8hY4vik9sAsmgS/m1asHvgVTCks52F7n/9dhnBBzlD5m7OOWFvKC@Ga2rW7ELvNolj1fJfOKIkPa0OLmJW4TAVt58hunB4uMtP648k@a2IWINRc2M9bCTrN8vlh8YzJ1ycvVApigMRNNry51Jr/nP0I7bOWfIovdmk07g74CQ/6gP/4i3MY9VJTx01RUt4DYxWfWTsNcfuQVIXek55aPPZ6FS6TMYH/FnUMoiNrgN@BogD6TQcDzswjxqZ6pvEqfT48yT5bFyjVjQjHGM2dWPqEzl/ELusLA4nMQJLGon0U5joXnEyhdE8ae2abtBPWD8yp5onRgFrEFge5cs@UDbf8ohivvNXCHQnjZUTg8AGMp70LEquPHRO7qRqJGTAX7ieMxJgVtpgQREBvgUP/CTCRx5yzQu0mk00iG/M@hCATlP2W1biLefyoJevEidC7AnMpc59xM1v@t4xdIziPMVLRymRktzznnXjR@HyCQ39jYTT69dv1HTaXEua@znT5wwLWGK1Dtz@Zx7ZuTRKWiin6bsQ47cQ7vRd8CRf4jDlCfskzQgaHny5@4NLFSRgNaD/hcUvSVB8wsEeeidISq09rNzjsZFEjVy8S8ikM22yC/ESQZCzXiM8QQyIsW3xw7dQwCr4NJBWEz6CVDWCKjsrRe7Bbl0WWvAsk9@ptCtZl1dZuCPnpPwXHd9hwnr/VmBMts7@pcF5i0qBhGt5CzkLNXmburvWvz2VlB14cJEGolejL@8R146ogAFYoNJzTG05A82ojLOANqrfIvM4gX0BCpXMhO@QznlMYeZPaMjE2w4Fif528NyWyRv6koyOz8K7ovOm4oVJmzcj18bGSDcN4XvTQ2/GbKIXsZe/jZOw4l1XFYbFoTykh65N1EVFgwS@FuNS1rN80U/MUsZfMHctkwfoA@givjh88aQn/84Xq3InSEZYRzVcEV93SCXI4FdhYf9uWswBXnbf4z7fNQil88l8gAqTRRZJyGMf6kz9BKG5X6jo0LtBdYcDXBlOAk4HyJw9lZLnQkABszs6wzaY2hwyXzS4zDkuKO3SObX7RCkx@tD60SseoHw02PrIwnatE9CS7GA2fUzGiDtT6iUtZph/K@7ngzQyf8ucxkk/8PK4VOhy0otDPHUB0KSdRdaAcJVA2TyJPWX9pn1X40Y83X/TDgvc7s4oHXnYR0O5pDjBafLtVF1JAlTOctF5jOeBb7toPfGiF2QouGnQeSDrEtI3n9pKmx60NcmkShRZnaKGbTFBRG6/uy9PT135yc2Gsu4/b9nV5g/uWaPPRSLNvzJ52KlLXIqyJaPGmhehkZe/XKDnZ2lhWf0GeTscY04iHoraCfDejge3Q2hYlUn07K6xA4jSk7nl1X5/ShaXll5wfEaoZ4abrDllUAlvenM8GeKuNkQtcV7lxNg@94fSIMxmpcJOT9gEu2D5PUPHJKMif4wEVbh8l02aNILplRHGyDzs9Qf2wn4NCp@9ux8DLGzDdocQW9hC@02e@zL9fglAvYyEMy4B622ePFuAwiTEzAILDu9RVT5GdCN5WhPuGg2ry0H/BuLL6KIHdVgsFVokqSKKFMXY7IpNc9wGUA3Guqm8bz7KskQKrpxkmp9ingyHhXPKtIw5PZAU9Eud44/54Ucr/PpyMzHXoJwxfb7Zs3YK21Ofv/EaIfl5toUHjl@BkU4VnrId2TAYBDpArOJmxNZdoAznt6RS3/vpoSNne/bGIlqATul9Pw5a@dwjAZOoU62Tzpk9IwjSfrqV4vB6QYF5ftigq7SiTsGzHXzfzInm0rbODIyjyVdOpuF6uIsNUMrxHt/j07JlCK389wM4zE9Ne@jC3QUfAbpCRk@AqEJeR@S3HG@tiJPY1jZ/bxPKSzlFbLj93bfRE5NByYYj8sszUEcuGDmrOHNlQY426ct5s0DZStaDiaxVxYc9hInRX3t@wA/HaR8ATv/KquXVqFCcRlCdaS3hgzCMdCpVnTfHheddrmzuMqXrkVO4Ui49g7PMdc9iim5txnrbsgLe2IJOwW2csWDiLoHhaJSbdLK51QhgKGlBpzmJvLC5fvYv4m8YVKVQBUYTvCnx04Clwjth7LWEQ5UO38GIAGyYUmsy2EU0Z2/NO1hAOrbRsXFtu7XhYP@fQRvFRinNNPW42tiSdQuZ6jBDCgerwNsI5DGHo1kZrOG8QK2Ga0K8BFTCf8bp6hvm8VL/6dXnYEKWGD5U@OhYvnES6pPvANsfwnoTERl3y9qLWE3fmmIOJ6dnrBE20M5zHTGjqbEjhccqzP/RMVwCcbaxSo1mPYgp3ubkFM80sBvujkj7RBFfHDxtiBeSpGDbJ9sjys6wPc04qC6t6lqhZutCuBTeCtU4y1xhbmiVC@A20FC2G5aao5/tMAs4sZYVWbIfXjtPp3LuHOLy/g8wLPj7t35ufImhsR3g8@Msa4K8ISdxou3PS7wrXo@Vm2ErgFMwV@UxCqvXqFVkJKR8/vzaMf7Kx6t1ZRCfsHTSnamEk2DeSr62uX3LAyospUl/UTSjboGo6BhrN/8KiQo4gdiTlLZXWgg535dtqe63sdyzLhvS9kIB5evZX/Yac9IxqYF8s2ZTDaDfEZ1ghhlI22/85iGP61msoF9HjZfpstWar8e/TthntQ0zSrPeHzI58JL33gf00a0TyZxFyXqGGOb2eXqfudnBNQNbxFvyC0c7C9HhOP3qX/QN@ky@P3l7Qf6V8I/MDv1jfPHxKfkgeyWkNZelCrq3utwDuagORhiBLOQXbJ8rtJfdG4QCutmof8bgKPUGaJ/VhpagfiM5mem8@37z8PfB9M2B7wVyIfyVkBsKzpLDqnjUe3b/kmxQxKbrQiez9m9qRr@FsZKFrNe2EbSzdj/Fe33tQIs0IaliDJiwsKuh2O8vB2aqU9WF0YmRYVCcCSresNPQ6@VPEE/ctkMM3NNMQJvky17oukt8mRxQLe4NuS7EsdP4ygRzpkD9UG16ynody8LsobKKCUwQpFPj5vDLoEZto358ky7r7YzjhPQwUNYDaLh@SoVbaIpsxb4p2ownQVLfxsdlZo0Glz4XdmTQLO7JF3b/SQeQq1Ofw@EYd2QLw/PZkgtZzi0erZomrrwflx51mV/QEN51ljyxsBG@C58cqMvtnXRFMw6lb@krbQimFXT94oFWrXRcGmZSuQCJqNFtA8ln5Nwya39UwDOE20JMSBT3fpYSocz84syPsUQlfnNdJ@Wv@ZjbjZuH@YvdlWUTObN9cpjb3Oze4qwAt8iO99Ish7JuHYetOP2B/3IXAL1rGkZKhp0WSocL9ablaWk2AQjO/csKur/p591I/qOe0zkitkBNXvpPtG7GSJJSYWAta0bLQBs/nlqcTIvEkB7nQ9J6cYidFvgFHAnx50TzXtWRX8sytRFnG1k64m@HqWwaosc3K10YGa0o5eLPpkqYX9fdEVNGYLznAVc6vn0BQyLcI@JhJgTNS4frJ0R5Vjsh@bBoK@Ad96XcFP450/lKap@Q624AO44knS/f1u5A4NY10j6zqy0jHPn0gjOh/FPcU4BXSjFHHLW8C1y9g/PLRvdsjD/DTg5iLJI8wlVSmfKKYQ3LyhITkuWV5XwAHQqkZB7/ILRO8gXs3vHSdJ/4q2FMgZBolzem3RJyMow7Cum9olkpwjbVqE6JsJLzqqXwxnFizqkzg3kghT3wfdA1fhVPOR1MqVE/gDPiz8FrOJ//cB@h2aCBiAc6PJurGwIBpgKws1SvIWvVou5JTICeaaoDLScDWsKjnq15e2SGTGYw7mVtUs@h7gWA5Q@0QaOahYIfuDvXqletwCntmcohEf2hybhru4njspjUHa3GDRICV01YZoxPoNqQ4sqzHDZzLnHpgb75XfGWuxo/rWT5HAvEsIfcQq9IfWBSRiZkNp3yFE6EKg@XZZECVP7IBYmR0NHxfh6zhDNP0G4OAZtZB4tABOkpPdDLeFSaZp67SFxUu36IDdy8Ysqwe6/vcujV6P@HSRbkIjPF2xCwI355ZuHAAst5CO1Dp5QVkQKeFWifShMoEltwJQgaejxtW5cfbgTetrd4oNSkSuaXi7SW//dftB3tMyhoxOTWBL0VJxlagHstfuSEXFug8Wg8T7jFg8QZ4F2JXVPTG02mi6SNWRzxBWEeg6kcKhF8E6RswjcdtWbiSi89VYLZIR4eoBSy/6D5rLZDI/nqCM00@TWmqNntWhoLPfquVU2YE@Yru404@TujJs5NQDJzgQiNZWZ2Q@HNcpRuYL4OUXfCp59r7hE2a8YpDI0b9Jj1L1nyBixeBDQLvj0LWB5xIV1DcQ43wpso5xQyO6gknRUEvKSqxp0VwLzOoP8hm2XIz0QTEx2qLvXl6XQHyrYzudGwZpTV9zpPkI34k0bxkucqaId5C2dT12QDRTMFnaVxLJzhxf4EZUKosIBOQ1cd@5bjhPAQbzET1ZZfuv/L5dKlOEIZRpJRSKUvETFDF2pT34eXkPNV1suYXLNFmPejq6m/ylwe2KNA7@@j2fvKrtEaFaPbApWdDYHvxUAAugF@t3HERs9aMIltyZTmOraqrX9wCZfbbhS8I/ZSoxAQLlMWAEfndr@RkGc762NezJcXbDib2qL5vNrCbKSq/z8epADK02HdEqni03OrBMs5yJo0rhWy635Kdf/4PcyTZ5MSCN89djU0Q6igG6WddazH3qpib5nKc5EnpZMfh3D8iv@HqEEOvis0KF9FOtdzY3QyM8/obYA2sEyPfHr5cEAd5GXEgpVXgyjI7sMXXIxLTj2i@VTgzphgwpGS@/oFKns2aY38L9Ihnw2lWXZWZjcr3mXE/32C1iCEkzRvIIjmoh4Nx4W8MCQ0sCeCPucNbumkEyRzWQ2XnyZGAh0YPvllPv7MoUPVfvaGFvRfBWobzm27c/dX19A2NrF9Rvu4gH0kYVuh6uQtMFGYRUNcwA4SYArcYXhSHVrhy1qfr/hePASHEVzGXJ3zCFguAt94DmM67X53/gtYkGLSsKSNtMwPakR05VQ6ydhxRqq/8AyBCVm7Asvynr3zuXhvx9ucoR0aJ7s4d3u83z328NxIdvjuNVlJT2VcMFYI6hJyZNvNedE0YPkZ@cpR3tm9D2Y6iaZnAkL1mnC6E8EjhMd863Sb4@qFv5OnFMfNCl5XlhjDYBW/mMHvMWP@1M@3D3CSryqrvW5hBcxfuh@2tEZTNA@EFoKgcxcRAUVCDsCUJxhD4rIJaouzAuKsZ4YjIpbSDiWYybjBkunTUANDa8iPQwhJMi2VxDANZVSCq4wxKeQatAQ8A0uznX4/e0xKJ9Qc0b5GpvtJSXdr9yJcuv1sZfXTUNOuzCmu4HszpPlS0a/gIVJS7MDtOOw0Q@KHOLg51dTvEyR0k9ME3qP/w/gkGt@nNbVZGyS9zvtgJoZH1a4i6VIJ8JSbnhD@6CSxewYud9UO4ksdnYipj4/JaM/URbjCVdR6FSNXn6nu21QV/FAXgMG5R6q9ddHFXTEuFoukunFG3/SYpq9kV5aQ463ji04mF@nx2sg7B/a5z9GPD0Oa9PGPVEYV0PsVTdeEV6cSbljz@EPLCBu81VVuZxbtkVvcJHYQpLLhjM5sNLOWZ2@/8bEfX2kIdDadiwSvzhnf1JiEvW6ydcrIx2qE@vI6lbEecKhC1ZIlmfAu0gwZxIgp@r3UKboLjNcqFoZVVhS3lEg@9HEhNBdRPj@qHMBBkHqqhBvWFpFTWuVqp5yurAtYq@W3I8H4N66qbLGqG/QpgBQhsueTV/qarl/3fi6CVzYl7JL3cRIlBR@oiPa6TnqXA0fESZ97cupkhKOCl6r6Tez3iT1PNjIxsDrnzGjpzn8gjfuzXB3zTJKQNWkzjq@iThJYyZ2PpuE8sSRWDnEseZgBudd7qzH9k/it5krel8InPhZTfCIEpFJ9N9QUUu/Yr63xdv6VqwW0Q0Kf8w3rJjcNz4nP4cjjxOJAU5gkHqm3hBRG941BYrHsmtVdexu@gOVTBZ9DmUHSHoJ9vcY1LxXIKnehNsPZitzzz1QRChdF8g5cr8p5zdbvmZLXHYru6kmEESWjRYTBhXTklU@Uyt5tauhcV@cpHwSh5MSqr7LZ8zMY7uLRi/ib81y492ZH86drwUhOyaE@z@2NK7jnhDml5ncGbjrcaBkT2tTaEnwTD9q7QkpbaiwdG4VheLYytKolcR10uTgmOV5u1btswUB1eBY8Rfu6EvW00mw3Pp4CzUhuKjBQmtgRZbgeQBpHm3GaNZOqRXF2xlGarJ4XRwwMa5cUFtvFVLj2xWACL@Jauc0C8net4HjlhxaWcJrQVO0ejHZXPpRheVd9@OM4ZYyPFdxrSfHfdjPdVxilUC629WULpsM9Quak5d65gi28kB8QanG9WgFrJRLU2r9UGAgA0XY0xUPSY50JpQA47Sv4s4696c44jcylQIjFv5mZ@5rQqzVIaB/Bt42CiJ/o3XWu@9lpwWTwIML5EH5AqO3wvxso8LPohtGV@4S7GeFD7DfjDuqVBceqlyXSVHPwkPCW@Yj8@TXIootqiJ@tMSFStfdL0xxttE0hJ8Ptwr5vAEShjYa5DUkMPZSreYD7KPJpKAVJREnUrnrUj6dG2reSZoI0HbEH1TwWeuVIZUUqkkW4wp@@jsZdp7nvXWuYgv5vKxJn@NvuGijFZneZKbMg8SgWXJApYTLFICcvqErv4xnR8k5q96GgRvnYYnGYIPcxGrz3o389HSpOP9gutbt47s0shtDRS@oRUNU1dKfMZ3xznlcVodHsSWzRdLvqlN75cnddVoAGYXVIPGMORqqHD/SaeBMvv4unUrofTxUxOmNds37UJe2LdsYAMFr2vWnmSFO7L0YMAhkv@9tYiRpUXLKQ6yta8ptFgv2CwQhtv5uapQ23y9RwRH5ny0L1O1OyZLQZGUSraKQq8fTi0Ts/xWeGyqV8CkhwbbZg8AZHYD9u82ZTzBEYO2eNosgb4rmNA8KuAj@Eth@iVKBIbi@/Zki3Yr@xfyQLGeCFwgN4X2PYYuEDeQoGfjVqbCoLnavcq0nIoOLu5zD/oVW561@J/oFy@o8ov76DTy18IeETy@S1MFDRsWcp1sQye@hFdO0xJjv4z8AKw8vGEiy9pPXiCwK@TpcTQbSjSbP2R6JzMTg8RXS0DfBHOqKOn@1apoqKUNZaK8qjTvXnLdX9AVOIuAD6Kba80DLQszbgkn3yT942TlwPaFcUOGVj/PtBlxMHfFmakPQllk2/i1C3kBlAbIhC0Al3NIe8qfp7x9Nrd4XBYuY1KdRm2zEHHVB@@a5qrP8xfrPP8@puCbCO2ukrWxtpEWzk1L@xl22zAQ/1WjTweguj9OhWIVxL5ihB5Wa2oytn9WFP@7SrUUqjKQpJdZzKEwLmyfSabZTn8CC@XpCwTF4TLft51yG5f6ZbyYgAC0/YNfkD8K9Sn/rMSQvr64DXy1PMLjen4IZKqEc5qojWmO5Uc19uwRnF1oWB76jI7VB2Dz94JC/01@0F2mnf0gFl30DdMMfmb8zPPGS9yxW8O@i@bAeE3o9m5qCrGiHjz1g6VwdY8Y@j2yqS8i0iGaDkAPcywMYm3ASo1szDwFxdckE6cWJcjjfOQGMDz7BkuDFRUlbF7qXa52M9IQPnmZXCFlh9UK5PsXfwpUyvfToxzaLYAcPfrfqsqPr5uUktlPTZv3gKpwseW2tDwfCySKLjwEqzHTbDKU76S4SIJcxeu3opppftnt3xOX1ZyNgtXtnneMDwVnRs7D9hEMO24Xu0pcIgtSPcu2oqrJq44oDIU0P1yI@moTAPwlSIFllHUsg4Kbzv@rSvDqV58JnIDAKNFcSyRvoONSTnO84ypyrrelRIssQdNEOU9t@mU7q5fyTB7uEm8F8RyH5dG2wcAEBqmMzZleEgDwbvMFMFYAyrXAIJnAT9G0eomZ34foJXW2j/8j00rBGN0CzYzRJX8gkVOw05aruYWZetjrfenbMvijIlm4WspIm6AIJ@JS8JhwKvtCdmFX3odEfGqWnBi1CSKQk/99bsL09vLnQP4SZEFZPNCoKaaHbgdO0FGQjV3IRd2Vzukl0si5WrXqrsI@RnBR3J3AE0oqKBEq11fqYlgjOOObl0QS2TfFdUbRbha8wHR2paRCHWVmZZn1rw5y4MbMdgsLT9mf4K4k1RTklxUPlrio0Nl9cOyOKstdaLqOhvZbKfIDsKb60cNxh79UbqoWw3UqdvyA/Fe56fcfckKVq6aIcbaXYgJXrkp10gnbd2sJF@iilqEMI9oCu082hjMWtYh0vuJTeXobe5w1lFeKZ@WOxaOgJcUR906UipI0ePD2HKUwe@20njmlxLxfo2R@jpR4lYkxwitSI0w4oTmb999eY@uSbMhfWRZlKZgiybubilnIrORoWnz9YD7RgzN2KsSWfgE0cj1eVtMiyhEWvvXJAfzxoxWuFiwNahZ0nFQdpYIe4@Q1YseaGtncGp9fPMeyrJs66YMFW9kkM7ECkk/hj3hoTSOIBOVELMDIG5SuFKYwOWjxvhlbyGXW74@eFv3n6bfN9/H7lEGWHWRk4W0uliix@bEYPkXDWltc/St4q57iKH/6HrgiJMtB49MD4r986VY7a0q8l6A2pZXfpajXFq11rdKvFFE3JGTWeIDX@eYVUi3cnNcMxXir5qlpEhyILxnyAhfijtiABLz6@nxsBH2q4@7UkBhpH1Tu@YqJUgiI49J@AI1g8wLPqJGJkgjY6bDyHMK0AOPEoZyWOFlZ2hUioMciagToEX2dBV14b73TCNurDS@5vW6Gmphl8HWtlNTS6sIUpaG3DjoRyH@zFfl0X4xyEz4Y5cGRciZeovTC3AMcVwmWcI4sqVB7SKKCxm@wJ5fa6I@AQtULZ3LiRFdy7WYOyEhyfSptbDAOq5pBRBZ7hpogktCiO8HAV@YZjv3V000zDGgVdMdbLXB/bEorMuu5TRIB4f/AKLjAP77SVC9pX1sZVX6TXiO8fU0282U/pRLkrYvue5Fb7qliif9V@PsgxRNX5TA5VizE30K4oceu81zoYjVUBxoEwMcbEMBw0zR/LBOw9KziqXfbD4JzNH2MdkAOiG1wczBVLAl6cuI@OvyPlOHocyiESyvgm0NfRc1UUO6qRep9dgzTa@UaRG3LypZ/gzdum3AQjTYwHQ3H/tLt14LZ2l7bpyCUuYAoe48fvSERBFxbpfiCWItBMMLAxjUZH4uz/ONyXk77Fj4u8k26KUwWt6eJryhMTxOA7hx5QAGfKm/pNfRfalVHfVBHQQkn0PXb4DVqXC8mXPYY/G9gBA5YASGSUL7DuGEg/wcmmPNjHC7dIAzturLTBbq2Baoa1K66Fy14exKCkhLH9/W7Sk/M4JstZzq9NWegH6cAPkxRfrtJGFiovS8kD5x8nW1IFg3nxBJF41RFsWLsZ93bfC0dFdOabRU0MRv2bYR0MFIEhrl8CBm1YdjJdckH5p96tE5TQvl0Q66/ieOWYO9AOtVksAVdupwdO2bQbLE2@97Djrr8AwnofgWFZdRH2cHAA3knBGhu4YyehGgS1nnMpgCJyAGTAcrttqvGrd2v/uPIfxsqqu0RpYQ6GvV58qhGgB@R8vOHCnFtiVdcXqfKjTcKlL11ULOyPnH9pFF5S5qjSBB5OG0CB60EUYnplPMR4P1M4TL/TPZt4xOHYfQqdizbVpgAMHmOUYli7jyuknjv@@1FaYRkz9Gzq23moph3SX3w2ISq3hIyjmGlOXTe/G/D69RyyoxTsRqudXzIeTODOwpvOTnG6IScA1dGFwti37pLEGmL19QoRZyRuUEr7l9Kn2UZroeWUcNPp7@TBBLX9vJPiUwQ6GqH2TNmCzHU4xyRMMQUxABIGs@W7fmYrop0g/QPU5OEliN2kXrah6pxMbiwvQRIIZHx7UYdxczDIp8URIvws/usczYqeV6AJgWpyrPemzYqG9B@V085jI/xBL4INq/XBcc4fT0ZXd/OnK5z0WvDwzn0F0EcBwQPyfuFwxYoFQ138Wi0r8Pa@w4d9cbdhymQW5MvSN37natnFqfsW59iv2w1jeZwh@j1T87Mzkd2368uh0GQMxfik6Vpy0MTYuuKOhT@vZPaQc1@fwJZLajGFnRU4MJqciZgVMid0q6oARDgjMABRgSP8IvpR6Bv1BxNu3iuRD9o5S7ldEOXjC9sqRb1Pn@k3T6HuWsVqGod30DQCN7iO2XVraKXnEHjNJsnSYL/80OHv5ZAyNp5K@KLCNJ6@@5QD42qgqB8AsykadI2OwPOt7@yH1UsWlcSsA3FHSd8xEkCDgCtejF6rcvMRnKVmpdqzdVvEXbmNJIeDJHIlYkysk/umXCvIyQUK7@UAJ8Ig6rji8QAhuEbm9rITR6RAcQq7S3rKyyBALp5a4aeBVqDuCQqKfAblZbB7ORDFqESrci0ayISDkxXQ33aLGzLxV0KVM2inewV94pb4WpsjfB@AHU5G6q0obzD6JKpMz3fqtnLKCOrwxiD3U9oONp8vGGCsOGHxoXrxZGFgKpYUvjC1kOGDpxC@lO6ALrAI1N@QhAg4Wjfo59qVyGY0RbbFjvyRNtXp7upN@ryuctMS3ZRxoMle@vF1W9um89l27vJ@@eoUKZClLW@cjba0sHXce98/bR6GTxsDd90wgEWVZ5qZA@TCeU36uA6wS5Aw3n2pFzC5L4/gJdp1YM39df2y0ZbfUrIRGL8J3mPrunDChXeZk3PfQlSeqJhA2JhprSMPWt@@4pnSvIHj5aA6EWHtaA39eFDtnKFL8SFpCSiXDiDsGnnQsXR8TKYkUK658Hy8ASlAekjKuAW2L5FoTnjozqxxlvFv1C1OMNuYPNellacGZsMqi9AnMWJRN4X/TIbKOHHSMiB07lkV3ptFY6zXHY2iVov9NB8NrLEv@YGxkK2akhUQteUQncZQtG75jQEDyVvLHHtiltqMpV6xMkopXaBo3DqIhxVeLaSRANM2Ir0I86vtp@7t8uCRpleS@Na8b4ecUyxBeqogvT46prsVXq2VYeCF/m67V4SD8V6Ip9qdyF1KWFgDlolg/abRylzYkQB66HXkYgfjtbFZrySTaZK2ykTM6QjFq2Z/mdZQM6S@OaBsOF@f47adP3nhOxIHz9FGKGahE0ZNgraeqlhjyeYlm5/YxMQ@1HaFalb3ziATE37lA52@pndpxGLldyQnj05MtLxt7Lq2@R2QIxGUtdFZ8/6NesyZF72NNqaUtsRi82YWVYRXm8mwUKV8HrWtYliky5ZUANotiL6yC6c781qcdIPuKiLiuAWHK3taTCe@4YDl/3hmFqGg175NrNmhhBiTI31FaA614Pqf2gfCuvD@3qzcNOk7jy252mvE0U9@P9rM5xNDEmu8qpPY@ssUtH@GRiKPhZ4vsolTN7lxvmglxkWCAy/UcuPoY3XqPfMEx0T9365vCJhaPQJCJPatYGh81dB9jPLpaRDyo/SM/YVuFVONfvKZxVnH7xUIObkgmUCOHi63o7wjNlmAztOXdFobDp5NM0iVXymlYZi2oi0ZxDm3YQxhxpVn1z6fjVviLunl8/1evosuKQXQHrNXD7PpCviPR1zbWWuB12zzvxkY@DFO5C@7DcOF7GN5Xi76f4zPPInUH485w4WDv7hYl6@BBjcteGPtEP@kmQrOkqyIGX8ofuc@Iv5FFV9yWGktyae27QD@Jk/kb/wIwpX9Sh@K4mUg1HHo2uzpF6geOXGLt2RZsqKWRXSs9XLr7bVEq0gNlC89E8BWwjkZMJNQBZe9n1zqZtIHvq6oeB5Gaqk0Xwv0S@68ccVWbgpV35yOCTLMlp1gpCxGKVlHnH96xTlH2AXNksQ5gnCy9Pp3EV5bTtkv5k8ZofFG3hZ9qDXXyBz@AdpIF19Z4X0zG/IT0YCkyvgQMwyC7QyJOWMdwX43j5ZTjrvfFaJMBPC/EQ/9Cc@ZKuUO8ae4UomcvnJ0YSUdVWj3zrs6I5SHXPbWts3ghePBWoMn5PN9kUMnV9XxwpeR/qjK/2xDOa6V2pRPbYXzE1QG5ZHE0FM4SoMYwNJXurLfPEYvZgzalIadvHFnS18D2YwMOSEcUnw0YR@AU3pqwiNtNfrVdykTME9uCTD3vVoPG7Ie1GXQfgVe7iEYeU@qphIe/0OwgTgMlUTjhTWQiPXrVs@vqBvT2Aq7SHhHrBBLmdcEt162LA/RJSsvzjvhL5HIdh9t8fXbnrG5iWw2AP73o6YH@aOKVY2l9wRC752Ko7UiLMfJPBWXpPswEdgaVHS31U0NC@HbMWKW3sWGU5C7tH8Zkm4Bf1uRiJBK8OHrIXQiNT28iehxHr/bt8WyIGFOsy34PRfTj56p0Uf2Kcn/pYHO@K@swWcoIvn@upTliqOaupa3@RhydgVSA4K5H2m9gu2oXygHVOKyEohhAKwU6Yxdj5MTN26fEA40vpTG3t9w58247rjGynsCrJE3qT/ak0@aXVxNafdrjY4DH@wqwtvxQfHcr5OxIIxiTrSM8SBlnAaGRuUQmXB0J7gb0N@xk34YiySMEZaBq0hUs1TVulsaqRGuIGvPiguTJnChvrRBpOXXFHMiR8DA49/2mUERC3W8OxUpmt2IaZO3OKj28ytxJss9XOdHUsb0E2mh/BJudXIKDgC5CgMv5ENlQDreaRlKo05e1bKxNO6A0pT3r2IlNmWt3NYHs52QDiVJY@Q3bfH6@0wGs4wzm2Y3cjQu5GbWB/MN@KIuBBwH6MC6yh42hvLpFKqf0HyY1/oAuXLliaZh/JOyDPHpkUYMweN/HPoS3SGSOpUHzn4dOToMhhoHcPus82ZluDnxi3tkTWiSX5lY/1UWgfoqPn1pVPtJuNoz0/j1VNrMLSkhqOlkFa6s0YrAjtIgzsjVaBlCvLPsIup40NDsY9ozzpiWcmx5HRvgOUnXrT@O3TDp3oxFSiH8eri@OsD4EzRk9zV15OE45VDBrIk6uJBk5FpLAir0cQt2TRCWf7FKuPALQivQq97i7Sz@MmRkIUK53KPWmZ4LLijI/tsmouVse6A3Be7YC1@0y7WHxDs375hDil3jObsoe30au4vuQhMz3y3T/RiPaMk1cNz9uINOaD2g/QtMDj7T96CxRmfEUCj6UEJPzqFzgw6AXnyu5Tf@q0YPjuRNlaiijh@bKID/31XulXmvgZAXSBbYfFxqOfnCeqFT7l3U5/62zNcOdQBktnBcLDc3wR6iLLBrInB9zVyTgZuCGGEcpX9pA7c38z0b/9Hhgt6Nd6GFB9fqYDd3zUKjZI8DtkxbfBYvfLHGSIxfpDw0ggsH7itrZNWV0ZJxGcGo26qge0IBSQo/7ktkaDsNZUFszGCAnt9yqbLBxm4CgzjlYuUDuKP5pt45pq6d@2RZvy@z5MZ20Dz@pW7ORojzXMfRDnge4dufldQI3AYhosYxHXpLaRSxwOpOUYncYK1E/iIcA5DvBGS5f9KN9@cO1B6U8@gF57iPXS@CIY/hA9ZlAMlK5BNjR2zZ5@KYhgleZNX0OR8j0AOF0iRw9yelJGCm2Gr/@rP5LwPOG2iA4lDiZlOg/niESMk933tPasZ8ImNzrQh4zW/XIe1QVuH8hKlkAsuX@fbZxeQCoQnRHEH54j4OtGU/r1crq1tgke4p4Xnb@3V9prTYoGCPkBlQn3o8Y/9/e7ptxBY07tcP8np2ANWI3YWVjTcEw@/qAtfMs1MCzRkwi1glqeorD3IYaywXHPz6qrNpfdSsXdd8ZtjQstrF@J9BJCzYXRT3NpBwbMDCpSwezSmnWhe1f2mpdD8yH4dNqn@7FQR1mlIqjrBPh5xXnYBkuzJnB2RPfxrrYWLLfJQw/md0Vu1cqadSuEFPiQ4aiQ8@pHQfIIWqvB6eEtveDiCVwx7YNHVUL83YIB0aDEakLBAWJZk@@2VPQZKIMJao@XXF4AtNNwzkTjIDLQFrYvH2W6UMJTfA/JR0VeUWh8J/ZrHS8XT5eXNFKdJ6nfZuBN6HReB7GDu/X6p9hdo@UO0Jxh6E3XwrZBHviWvrKy6kirDuaQeOghTmSH3WMSaB7YXOlUREyTMXuci0fOGk8DUtCanZ30pfStvPIELneqKgBQu80EC7iER@DvQ7iAlCLywqy401GXUHZnVsmafJzx2zqc@AGrpm5wKkgGl6vQL3hSwUWnDlw5zFnJQCDDiQxdF21iwfaNEnLtmiZrx@5Mo57WSdkyq7VzFIcXFM3mjg9PNt3vvXEwCUgLD4VfFfC@iq/SidyXocOkbBhTv8RgFGlEdZJRyrwGp06xPioqQm6R9aDVac2hq57jxemi2G5qTQdnWqKNG1io9L25eNukL2OBvk6ozDZsWmR@g/P3ovJA9vM3S3refYUt5k0aRuhiiHPddWJJxsErkmwbgcLn3q0RoZOKChM9OAAR7W/qM1KBKz@mYRQ002axGc6mti4ndZ2L@ntfGVkwf8Q4T8laIhxGhh00RqM/mqi81IF6@Tn@GleVmNEU3oaRT/nFxxwp21nG9o6dKtGED9FtLtRDDG5KNCyG7LciFfdN31c8svumFnZLCLKObvtryAmT786WGTGCiwufzebr1Q2NKGZh0Gv7wiJGpz2Ktq36UZ2TY7IfJ7yDwbYuWlLXxAYCHho3Y9x06BRxfhE5sdtK4/Xsud7ad0P@8KEp7uqVj78fHj6t0HCj2adFCOm4KjrjHENGRfcTpEM1K0yw@gQVbPbDcJGAblUGDO5P1Obv20zgcMzYOAwCGEbgIchBbtYh2ma133Qo02GnXGql606WrjQzFs8WAeTW2qV5xkCX/GeqRIGsSNzKOgumU118kMOMXnpkszCOjMmlMHkgtfoyyx2YciRZOZDRZXk3y0E5os5N8T53CeL4UtbFOQILQ58QzogLyqCxDseXV24U9rskz0IQ3XrA27@wrpsHK3SSfbX@COXtKHqBTZ@FGtCi1AbxIrvo98WecYGq4Cct3tmVhSVWWtJejzKo1Beb4e4z1yKtP3NVMajXt9xGmhnGPtGGRwbt2hEpATHhlCjcAPiLGMLZLqXV9n/vFLZ5Lv0Op/KXpeKbWiUQeMqp1FGrKCPqrcM4rOAtZffVWwuul14Auq6DAynudE@j7@q9K7V7HjSExJNWVSQ8I3J9nNa@Q1BOEUM2GBtwfy0rDiBj6RiqAAoCwG7ReGN7kK7066VdJ1DOOJAunkYOZn@qcfdCPVXh@piC@cDgsRJQhrSdrk8593LzXwfPZwKNlaj4@2aAnPCpI8@smyYW4VbATEPkky8ynV8m8ksgaN6nOjLzOu63wTw/BVlt@lvYgs3kAb3KmbOgAYZt7fUR4e3v9UyDPnK2kXl592mv4muW5XJa@YTyXHCigfC8CRBPBNMbxX50bjekgmAtV/TNbm9XjiLvzzCIzJ5pYbJ3j0fFOuP5XCelbAtgG6GmwVMaz1wvIxTMDB15dJppumj2RBYB2mbLrvamxuetuQJiUZUPkNLTZiY0YIVD4@43wMF2BVbDTF3WVg26nalK/f4YIK3fJqxheH97S4GKjTH9vGv70S9FM9VNiIJOQWOe83mnjGSmfmuMeR2mcFxQFLehmZHT1tt35MN9Q4R/0/mazhiHUi1fc6lie/qQqKO2RDp7yqzzYMRir@9wqO4HhhHcJz9iownxizmpZvD/69k8dl5Hjii892N4d6EBKFGkKGEgARTFnHMwvGBoBjHHJvnyY/7XY@@@g0JV7apOAd2NZ/borWtY/GsZxhfL4Yh65Yk8RvgeTsWKf2AXFw3Od9ezswviYnN6xFkmHzy@/ikjtkeHSVT28zx673GqwYzEApFIcOdrwlTRLjDXuj220/k6j@FlAMVKiCSnVfBMJBvhC@VH9HaRW9FEtqz710uniQ11JLLhNVMxoSMC68OozjRvMMz8Ox1EeygYj8NTSyp1d3nug2dZDDMzHI1QXCetcEQLaJp6te0I9TODnSgxEKwHZEYhraaL7VuJP1c53C/FjV8AQ5Vj4z1KfcCuIyaExcppVtQnvFSY72i9aootkh02OusnumOhZ4g9elf2mLsaHRZasQ5EOuMxnjbey7h8ZfyEGZ/mzeGVa7pS0yszi9O21t7OsKQuHN7QSMWymEzZlY5Mqxoi/HF1CZQzQ9YkzY@eRGJAV8vY8xrzjsXCKKR4zZfq6A1Ie2Dv5LlhBGQHqnwcJJh53UnvE3s7Na44EUrbW@f0QtWKDjbULdwY3mfPpaTwQ2S4VCCX28PMyRIa1BbhDPUVee4Rhmozr@VHDdsTn6MJZJPgMXpfd05WUoGl3N3SIVPy@g3ZDxC69ex7Wo/ECviOgkHypuXpnL2T61KjZ24r@UEKokDdbD3tKVwbpxBYmt5Rmbhq9FJBwpBv@z6GHOB4AZ@1YHGbCWO1TDGSFt8arkOKBdwvOCEWWJVv250ubT1j82WMIN7NjxX6KJyV2BTmmkI49auvO3XGe7Cww0VT7lqRY6UCOehcrKuDB1f54enDxqJicK@XHqS1TJ3Sqww3S5cHakK7Om4dYHC8yK4Xviqt8p2I28T2tGHlmV1czEehd2vV4W4TImunsevJ4SMDP2/GboyWcWEIDJmNq5NJ07uv2ISnuhvQlgc8K7fHfuseqt4bIQDILMpvQ1/qNMLEWU2BxeQyYKxyIBGjxK8VMCXdLkkd9W1fXx9Sfx@shZCXw9F8w9FNEHQyFKcGVZWNXCj0rSXPfNbnuSXhOD/2sRZTug6LSTfEtfv6sa@iaM2V9GSVUGihwJjfPWwpAmuvFL2F3oKTClimKQ6R8ILr7/eE3yWOxZYFdUvSYZdiK6mJ2DZfnaxelhEMAleNeqplr5tc1uJZx9fPTfEG3UCCxUe3tCuCcY2l1Uzfpl6z3Yf@QofEafOifrCjfrGEAOfQiTrWnm/DVpwiLYra3KpMU4J6grSIlj5gxsQ7c/HPDuQetwXuE/E55gBBNdtnQB2rWoUIf1NbL@8QwTXHZCd3Fixfrg9/vQup2lqVlmGVHVmBoXDBpXA70@kdIVP3WvAP507mLXbhe6ucVcYc/dNXWF0A7lB6EF5Jc4GzbuyXrUxA3o23s4tKlHt35jsvh/lSFUwckhEaNqtKUX2Sum@QCh29qnRqDiShkM0CblLte54QkDVTsbhqg1t6xupycQjX2lFuzHsUeBHfcvFCySnbiJgJ3dYRJc63GgkPmW3M5y4dIYsTMtD2KAj87JxR9NmdZJ7E4rLXzb3C2sjvz6LqIjRN3ox3yvbJqFe7MsaN4S6jGnd1uM9poGW17AxQipmu0M5vTCyTY9a/nRpzrSVoo9I7/f65ylB6jHLTAv/569cf/yKfr7AKm636433QkBU/SB04duEwHfz5m8P/hujnK97GCfwWzPOVVfMU1r8V@z91MPfDW3wQ/3zlxTgVycH/EJ6vYmwrMP9ExOfrb5IO2sYD5OerBlNetD/1lOery8EPqQcNbXWQ9nyNYDhAf76mYeumtssPZRwqH8DvNPPgbWh/ylnP1xL@pNn/71s04N@//vzrr/8A)

Create the Base64 string

Replacement of all words with uppercase chars in the range A-U
after that bzip2 and base64 encoding

```
$a=preg_replace(["#alanyl#","#arginyl#","#aspartyl#","#asparaginyl#","#cysteinyl#","#glutaminyl#","#glutamyl#","#glycyl#","#histidyl#",
"#isoleucyl#","#leucyl#","#lysyl#","#methionyl#","#phenyl#","#prolyl#","#seryl#","#tryptophyl#","#threonyl#","#tyrosyl#","#valyl#","#isoleucine#"],range("A","U"),$titin);
$z=base64_encode(bzcompress($a));
```

### PHP, 19920 Bytes

After replace the words with numbers and create a very long decimal number I can only read the word "leucine"

I have 20 words found that I have replace with numbers

After that i use [bzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bzcompress.php) and the last action was base64 encoding

```
$g="base64String"; # see online version
echo $o=strtr(bzdecompress(base64_decode($g)),array_flip(
["methionyl"=>9999,"cysteinyl"=>9990,"histidyl"=>9909,"tryptophyl"=>9090
,"phenyl"=>9009,"glutaminyl"=>9000,"tyrosyl"=>899,"asparaginyl"=>889
,"arginyl"=>888,"aspartyl"=>800,"iso"=>70,"glycyl"=>79
,"prolyl"=>78,"seryl"=>77,"threonyl"=>6,"lysyl"=>5
,"alanyl"=>4,"glutamyl"=>3,"valyl"=>2,"leucyl"=>1]));
```

[Online Version gzinflate](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82ddaedcc3578b66deb15b7248a16e395de046c6)

### The words and count

```
[methionyl] => 337
[threonyl] => 2083
[glutaminyl] => 724
[alanyl] => 2304
[prolyl] => 1834
[phenyl] => 672
[leucyl] => 3351
[seryl] => 1910
[valyl] => 2414
[glutamyl] => 2324
[glycyl] => 1731
[histidyl] => 391
[iso] => 1658
[tryptophyl] => 401
[arginyl] => 1405
[aspartyl] => 1430
[lysyl] => 2199
[asparaginyl] => 902
[tyrosyl] => 829
[cysteinyl] => 356
```

Comment: ("19 words" should be "20 words")

Comment: @GregMartin Thank You

Comment: I bet you can save a few bytes by flipping the array manually and omit the quotes for the words. Why the weird numbers?

Comment: @Titus Yes but I found a better way to make it. The first way was my first thinking and i have try to convert these numbers additional to base 36 but this was not a good idea

Answer (score 5):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 19655 bytes

```
0000000: e2 e5 7a 4c bf 5d 00 36 99 4a ef 2b 08 5d b1 93  ..zL.].6.J.+.]..
0000010: 69 cb 7a 61 51 8c 3c 7c 04 41 de 7e ea ed 68 3c  i.zaQ.<|.A.~..h<
0000020: ca 5c e1 c8 6c 5b b5 31 2d 0b 4e e2 8e 52 06 ec  .\..l[.1-.N..R..
0000030: 5e e6 da d5 f2 f5 d3 8f 83 a3 51 0b 45 5d 19 c6  ^.........Q.E]..
.
.
.
```

Here's a full [hexdump](https://gist.github.com/DennisMitchell/c8cd46c9b8eb7a1d3b00e5541c456b0c).

You have to paste the code manually, but you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bubblegum) (only shows the first 128 KiB)

Comment: ... Well, at least it's shorter than just straightforward printing it...

Comment: When the output is cut because of a single word.

Comment: Yea, bubblegum got beaten!

Comment: Can´t You save about 35% by using 5 bit to 8 bit encoding?

Comment: @Titus I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: would be easier to help if you´d say what you´re doing. I assumed you did the same translations as most of the others.

Comment: @Titus Bubblegum only understands plain DEFLATE and LZMA encoding.

Answer (score 4):

## bzip2, 15287+2 bytes

```
BZh91AY&SY...
```

[Full source (hex-encoded)](https://gist.github.com/Sneftel/dc58481019c421d01367b4fded67c39c). Run with `bzip2 -c`. Where do I pick up my "best programmer" trophy?

Comment: I'm afraid [bzip2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) doesn't qualify as a [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages).

Comment: @Steadybox Peter Taylor's idea of what "qualifies as a programming language" is a flawed one (see Bubblegum). In any case, it's not endorsed in the question.

Comment: Well, yeah, Bubblegum stretches the rules quite a bit to fit that definition.

Comment: I would say that this is not a valid answer because it's just a compressed file; bzip2 is not an actual programming language, it's a program itself.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino CPython is just a program as well. On PPCG, programming languages are defined by their implementations, which are (usually) programs themselves.

Comment: @Challenger5 You have a fair point, I see what you mean. But then where do we draw the line between programs and languages?

Comment: @Steadybox https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/8478

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I don't think it's necessary to. The size of the stupidly-compressed output makes a useful goalpost, if nothing else. If you've done some clever stuff in a KC challenge, but you still haven't beat bzip2, that's a good sign you haven't found the right approach yet.

Comment: @Sneftel That's a good point. I agree with you.

Comment: On the basis of the upvotes on [Geobits' comment](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12046/194) on my answer about deliberately making languages to create/exploit loopholes, Bubblegum answers should get at least 12 downvotes, and I don't see any reason why this answer shouldn't also.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 17684 bytes

```r
E="/Td6WFoAAA..." # base64 string reduced for better readability
U=unlist(lapply(match(utf8ToInt(E),c(22:47,54:79,5:14,0,4)+43)-1,function(x)x%/%2^(5:0)%%2))
D=memDecompress(as.raw(sapply(split(U,0:(length(U)-1)%/%8),function(x)sum(x*2^(7:0)))),'x',T)
for(i in 1:21)D=gsub(LETTERS[i],paste0(el(strsplit("phenylalan valylthreon isoleuc leuc val glutam alan lys threon ser prol glyc aspart argin asparagin tyros glutamin tryptoph histid cystein methion"," ")),"yl")[i],D)
cat(D,"isoleucine",sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FJnHjqzaGYVf5cojS8gmJ8keFFSRc4YZOeeMH/6aox6VusXe/GGtb1Uvf9t//edff6XxtO1L/u9x36Z9@@f//v799x@gkxE@N34@H24SNwz5lJ/qY53v54/5wI2K8cWltl32YWc7kSXhqm3bMfxeCy5hOItxGO6U4KNaKCvA0Ix6mWwVvGKIVaYflZbk12k3mgafgnBpkhIupzAOcC8wgvBBPkFLID@oYkgWanN5ndCZ/Wm5O9NPPdCEaFhL@myOvDCEYvBh6nHDBV5j0/9c@vKLg1ZnMVMau7snoaDEgASdlrGbiwfTLikxulBIa4/wdYRpKEYSlkEN6DvYb/PQkMow7FyL1MtSGP6XRbWK7k1OFQ7cuISg2am6xeei/8o6W7uHmbu6YcWJkJ05vtWq2EeGemCaA91OvgHTsB6Sz6BlqiW4p2D5Tsh9whgVx0ejYbwT7S0CGd8jgLy5fqi8ADutC5/WzhYfh4QBavz4Dn8QSjoxdd6SEIiJXwRwaxPJt55ueoN9E0R/uDcB8PpDFq6KIuyxHc6aZZ40zS5qzfdNshveWZY4avNTYJ/RFr/gkviZacU/N9pyPIF3xbFHKymhiLyD6v56rKX6VbDnuT9K6mY/J50ZsLSxEO37tHuNPqkU3FxHP/E2OfoTYK40pxW1CXe@AWn6BTxGCI2pa2kv57141a9s4a@WvszQVZZj1gH4iVP7FkQ01IbGqQGu3p5VMETjaEWhk9FxrNM2ciwrSIeRMj1wh0C6TW1eg1LCwuOnL@McNnDWC51zD0uQRm51DClhR1cpzCI@437UT/45ZjZe8SUdjZlKmblYrjsJZktK98qjdk8X3NJzV/QVZyJ01pmproNQnR/cxmWrPAgzHl16AfysSYHo5hLp@ztkPc20D1a8XcCqzmJ8Cd0CowLT9XTuxve1GtZH/kkSuDyomdzoFK1Ysqe7fG/@sKTZW5kMSFuCKxk5ihfpk64qH/tOD//EofROZhTyAaB7UukBM1DvPcCOg94Ph5obkYYuuPAlr23e91sHmzZsWbPXBnqrJ68Yugm/H@j3/JgU/sKW51MG0cUaLnV@DK4O6ZWUSygcmfKwk1ZZgx85aTfiDhKPJFSnshhbUvpnXL0hb0AXJgTC7fDdrJNMAk1LaKoHxE1q3BrpmQCimZw2YkdSnIUgxJp8mzRcWRNjMkSRpID12c9Bv7fdC@1GBga1f@ZM9PBlPOgSnz7VbQ05p8UfRybWZuAqqmOoLL6SKbZoY5q0wCud3WSz8YfqomSo5w94gNrybTj7Snj8HldE1RNJGurkdKIA6XcjCRsKiUxcBDWCkzR7@HuFAWVed1ujZ6rI2py0ZLlxMthe0B32JK5qCfq3CyUyWUd/XpwKMgVGldspr96HPpYGpTI@CZFp4amsMp0smhVM1Zd30h6gHcXt1JWCv7lIUKLV077@R7zA/TlC0OsWcSW/9EXf3pCoqh@0MpMc4IKUjYiIdJTI5CcB@tYLWX/Iqw8yDYhgcVu9YdW9CsLn0Bv3CqN9Kq0xxFRv77kU3ULivpksKbiuM9DaSMTCh5Y1GM/6Yp3HuU3ra@UcqUjOoNwEKcEAuRi@UHguwi0wzyUTKIqceZXsh@fKTyyppi8rXctajfsEBNMOc7bLNud8vsDhPIsOXefT9bwgd7xNZbhUKWC0lSgkzWGwwK8CNVvBacLeRQJBNb9lKVZ92UfDMFlKoN02MmVIVlfX8eAtkvNDcb1uPy9jyZ96T2RNW5ToFOVJojVzBnLq3nXfDE8fm47PLR1M21etQiV5N9c//UsILRZZUGqFoGU7FdtaXXG7JTq5wkj3zAVMSV8/Kz/y089D0GiUMSfJiKv5jJx7W4r2g19t/saI@mGhX0bPH8C@ts9oagm/jW2kjctGQIFZpxr1LWw321yELcwoHlj7JJwOZ0kMuzuQ3FbYS/qTv7RzKc4fLyHOLLNyuzzEReokl@adj/@Ot@Cr3QEYQOlfwRwkmRHXBd9AtRASaXABqAh0LC2S@wxgV1AKJ/14zKnZOgkLlKPIpG5RZBv3g6RK3ravfWNpIPxlpCGZTX72laoI6pWhCd9Pvufn3meZrgMYdGl1GXUoOCJjAcipr@BsES2z8IcyJ0WXbLQwlyUp@D2J4qfKV1tprwWjmcJzLI0T/MI/4BVk8BoOenZfLPORL3WoE8906@/EtvW0R2IrmzK5qsW8ybr@FGf5mI/@tET2yZwk/vCURmhOImTinS0C4xqyzO81/uPjDvt5tHOxZB16G/fpuHanhLOGdVV9S@evp9LwEXVkfaOaE3LR8zhwsJRBcxWWzJKTYNUwJPKVhgtAfME4JYGeiYyrI824a/wrEc0B1qE1KFrtv1OqS@iaCwPsWXaxI@5x@5MPY03mgZFHFbXqA6/hgd@YQS4jb5LvSpqHfyxpZM8aktK7D1qnIdi2jpaHoPJLzwMBeF5ZS9uwtZE@iycpJsfXHAOz2SYUWDg5MBk41/pfNyOhCAMzTcKInyvfLanlP3V1nrWUVXDsNYhY8R2ROsX/VAAhVerXWWr8CiZO9hpy9XAgTqeMWjkjxGLJOztGAuH5ij/7V2ZQwOhGE893g19WZrqbJZjpsSAboAQ/q7kOhC239DK3kGApZewt2Q9XI9RBirKctQsZpvY9JSM1W20b5AsGoOlfZ4/etatG@jaT6AgMxEfne9nIKuYTCTce67aLMb@IAQYP9KVYlExMTtppqG5ASGNUff1ZJXi7SzMNDKuFAwNbpMgPTc0UTLUJZN9A2884eYDQllT9IL@MAThzMHsQAla4QnKhl4nZJVkeO9hbZs558EVvIKJERuWyGXTeH0svYRpf4EVHKccFvn6cvs@W5FV/CJ@0BH4wH5JhOcYXECRMJEqrdbXcajyF6WlLJNWQkBJx02n6ya3t78GuNJnLnfrkJbfJbkkn7hUs71jWhuLdGpBz@E8GcGVn3QBongeQogAOU4tww2jkNGNQJRelv/Ay0drPZD4bKHxKE2vICupSadyl1bb2@wIcqN8cDV4raxq6HQPUJTNpkt4hIr/Gvjdp21GV8gFc1YQA2kJbpBWd37fEGdU1smtPTAcxSgaW8eQob7kzduRKpO3bMNWmOBTX8CSwsLiNt95zix3GQuVGjWhpL9DY6MG9YIaD1a3RUxlnzF9vDZTitfMP9L4MsVSHtLoskrtoXXNzJRRIxlVmHOFSp9cYxnQZzpPwW784SRv4EuwUGIo1InNEH6XdRNk@WWWcnxxX3Sywf8hU7WBFtsqCt6LpneRFL5piITGUerJraT7ATzsJUcwWuf4JaYUUDNUtQNAq2WEm4npBlXwVxXj8JPOgYBSELVnqk8ZksqqVP9G6buJX2ZkWDcwPYEjb/qM/yxk0SAdGaEIAd0TJZVcwnqpP1mZgIN/GkmScRTtwt5GgHgnoECM1D/aKNzRi8rmEy6FIrCXh8M/9fuhUpqYcWwpkzcNAcGAwX3uuy0p0gHfNmk2AeYKfkLEEb1pFi98N8WoGhXs49O6GQWflMORLQRFPRxB1BBy4hBjTQTaHZD3DgJ1MOYYQirhvPFKeCxDuWUm0OBQIqHSROg/Wximdw8vr5FN9t30vkNc@GPpb4wHcYRCDmrnk3gH7YD8LLuHQMaCv@LRngUFrnUi5a8qe0a2ByK8O5wxEjX15MUeLg5LttlBu8uexU38wpZQrFTiAq20AkMmE1NlCJM7X1k7YWqfDH2Z1xeGRRMPI9DmYzrLtYhofwxXD589PcMKcmCcinfibPrFhGA1@PyBor7Yc6wrktx79PZ8jGQcrbfTy6UI/Xuss@BfI83C5gMJhr0wNmWl@nDRWD7POa5LRErkoCZm9J/sHqiRTo3NgnVmvkhqP3hg3oMLKVZPAm8y84JJi4yauWQhiHKz37aQWXXxrlCVd9hL/nQSljQ5LrN@CWTGrRddlo@FGhCkVWXxE5LvkkIGr@1iFlydnIEIot8zvMDTkvhIENhuHgTpVabFSTGnmdQonDo36cOzj5lHWG9SK7/ay@i04L9lLfCmME914SLcOZpfRtFSABdqwW7hj@Dgs4t/LxmeC8cDZav3s/cDMrOBXZi2SKVLYUNGvfqNQe97c6ZnDRzIReVCer0kmbo/d6hIrRaN2Gk8i5m/MzCKfA@R5ubK/nV6OSWwBOKTonJbp7s@9kCKJ2Cp62X26DIgexD9PXRliWMjRlNdYbzRq9/I51nfUUlWT1kLlznrw1BT2BdMfrAadTsSZ0iHxxsLjqkSLexzrrpyju93AQ3V46Slja4W56sSP0Un3u5oitHy2eDtZ38SEARzCcoBZS0mBYIiLB0FuUal@RIhu0kCt@pdMlkTD97ascMEmYktD9ynTOW2DdOOXF@EQ0hjrbAz/Bd8Q/rDjNhJ2VtfH/EM8OrpzEmZEooJsJ3pCukBw/JwaDmQiac/evF/5RS@Mcbp97NLsj3ban9@sy0uodh79@IbC6yYIDHtZsO8z97a/Dq9JmraSDUO4vtOVVfg3TAuSyL7G93IruTPRkSjkpdXfDMtwHolRNoN8m/EVhp8Au6vJcOtysP2rnmmJgebDz0Z44h9oy6bQYK/xnj9SgW3zcaMlu1zhpdK8WjS/rOgYCKBK/B0398bmUy0@dJW1asswvWwTg8CihiLMz7fmtRMZjSmwFmOnOLpj@fGB5MgkBT0wcjJJKcyu8f1bsbMcoVn9KaKoRYFBwhCY8L/cPAujhlENB28NX5zsfKS4rFL9fZrn1PY4B2SS5Wa/YwhCK4HGSOsVxItT0uHIxoZf3simPrvilzvPIGlwtedgP34Qwb5N6B0oWr8yZ1YHxA1Ze7EVs@cGGybmpJMy5@cCbJL/uMvM4k3rjeRL2pqArCsJmPtY0DZvDjXKafKCgtrxI@9PyZ9nlZ7M7YMNhBqVufqQd518Dfh7/Do3MEz4EyA9EZedGhVQeBApLTTHYW1yHROElo7Uzjzg1YfxZJ@d@gR7yfFU/IWw9M02@AMj53VHwH04qTl2tY/PZ4GXgNt@Pq9WI3rX5CGxkxuJFAvcV7ho9tHU/IEfUXkch8alIHSb1zH9iD8zTHZEdmiRPJinKZc0vYeCF0Wg0/RXwKNlwqgQaoAdDr4ac2NV45A@rR4z6omyUM0W05KV58EhMPkLWkvYUWEjn1UmokUDvVBdPkwyDVgtW65q8dvydoqBbUbSaWLWivXmseut0s9EqrLvCo1doGAFzaQ@DAj8kQ9jyATgy907Y@etvew/waFpccldPXsafWE5JKjkI2enRHNihxvDw3FpFGlcEPV8bmV7HdL3lpo0w@GcR1tYeaD53H26JhMQ7jB8XqUvIytbL0i/9vq0UCF@qYrW0hw4soQiv3@6HIuNIjfureciv0UajOGmEvQCWr3@JyoxjI04KGHJAPQerCc7/7uBAMZm3e3FfUytirz0yAnB42CJck5olhSaMbwGso47xGSAzROy9TapOTM@GUgOhUHuWAe6ocuQq9IoV6p1UgADP@G9pysiRLqUET3VCtGTmSmepRQkJ@K/sNfJyCteQSBq@Wr183ReMaCkFlsTKkw15ZZwrYD2BHwbKN2veKR2@zfbiEP7nSDFsDzLoZcGQL60Ug6EtBdRp@@2XJTyW29hly/vQr9gmbu97fGdOLqFIZBqaEgE9RFW7Y8J0@W0CtaMdKnRqp89WnmGIHlhWY7e1a4ymPn7Mk0eSJU3SjSaW2AlVArAWC2Rujh8G2XzvqTEG8mT2llmnlVGtpc2DruUwL7i@hWLMJzB4RRd42eRlu996YyH7gD8Ah4g7fUiQXjoNM5E5V0fOpsRtJ0IJc4HpgJiX@Vr@uhrWGg2d4dwuFMku0KrNUBCj1mY6EB693DIutTSSN2hALCGZ8ow@Y1Bp4VXIGnu5jBxIzhacQDJBKpsqO68egt5/PqmF@cShq@1pqSbH4Ggz/uHJuTo/aBuq6OT1WAAdXFdH3pYfhpW@hktd8kreFNRlLo5hA2riNhjtvqRqX8sVigI4wgnjpsaesn1eJA0exVGf5RngiFyMA/MiTmoLDNwjzd05Qh79/o1eWm15RlxadJ8WVK2NuGZRW6vB5vnJ0AOKmy/p2zJw32mjTrmJ/x8NB@xk185yyLVhtgU/WyCiffDYRciSrDgcJ8vyMfiloUOPiSB7cavXbi1EVGf7JpAinR7RLmYICKYFtTFlIIZw1gq2nNUefl0H0D2ZVj54j@KT1ti6kY7Nj9Pp8yuQ0@vCXxhKAA6N2gI0hcawT8@qv@r6@AHOZZ6tReDYNi5vswBAQfUxosoHgMAaRb7Mq@T4zL@3agzweEhwnlnzhWhqe8KVH57PDql0P985BdcC9GznhzEextf4zRsiXIjqQrHwO/NbyNDJ6RSn3cZQvX4xJu6Hqy14/iqryrelt0BzuVImrKDUO6JjYrRTDdVlDr27q/@uVDKTsE1d6IU98nGwN@pZDntFSQJ97Gpdt2m3I@7ARw/KkVsFijCpswJiC9bH8HhKb882v28q1vsZ2Xdr@KJXNBKrt6JwhGD3DdYfpKaAiFRvI0myTe8UF2qfRu4iD4DK0PzVWTbky1KrbOGZKhZ3oWLf2idquUeZes8A4vPCSKcGz1cktpZphgsG6pSKXnlSu/KMefauO1jRhyXbUWo8C4rp0xxZaJ3InBf3m2JS6tfgqUONaTWQoN@HAx8J/4XEj82BLDVaiILQG2VgiT7jeQPATrux09VTPaIC7E@T5xoczTHu3cHcugfkcuGDIgUwYA9ktCLqiSEXF13eDSA7fauOOJdkfxSTTjorL6oGhCQ7tFTC71eSB@8Un4bKkRMSv6YaJgo9QRYXeEA9CKc/g@uVlGvlFsSLz3RqXhh3IZh7JvRNipbWndo5HZbTYsczKtCpadbf@TANg4bj2Ll7vFDzLJfww0B7w0cHtbQtaRSnfZJ8B/CZhRHZ6O7Rmg@iM4wqOiSNh2pPbzXsrbuofxrhWT3UrrsIWlcCSOTt3MB8g0C78dPSHvPlFUAgH/cxLwhzWjMfrauM1Hmd09Bx2x9kcU53I9IyYpPaAFZXT7bNpoiesddqbx5H21MKYzvkarUhDyd5i5FoLwjUzrtKFsVctYacLOZ81VVimTOOhGZImy7CB4XFgT12k73rKJquM1x/ZbL96Pdo1vuTfVAbC5JZWnxwyuYfSZcha/9QTo/loN3V7kZ5gj/nFOW2cUslYzanqevTXVUcY3KryRlRpUNn1U92cEXNwrROcNraL3qzyGEWrsEblrhABrqaTqsNvojaLJR8KIrkq/XCuzT7/553qIK@TnYxN@hISmxn/XdPgAqP3UXgOUCnHq8KXqGbaIQn5eEw/YROpEHNfhL/vlE87I/7o43KINarfIXc4sibXNsw7/5/i7enmUpGO3fS/rJ9E2pA9evFSRMNibTi8X/vl1CII5pl9dRTH4eYR68oaIbguf3vdPSAMi@ZIWdyTTlccSp@sdUg6pNOxVf1CWt2gNw3wwdAOIGUap5ml9XGnWUWO7MR4qk4SW19klmop@KRnT9Nw045a5GJjnAGuUZ8yk74@TLz/0VPY34egkRk3z4BQtP84trPcX7XQlnRAfC@DrPJHu4zpOeYfUy7OgZJba93tmFYxwCOqk/qW4Ghrr5@WeA4jcc0wXMCIiAgzlWFJFZPZSA0QvvS0Slar3gRzMgtO@y/9xTDKa9UoCaBMBBgSDFMWzCzbwpaN2GJaTfNn@UrHS9nd/s7oSjOPf1tio7clFxNBmuBRoHlghNxRZ/g2J0yl1bphQjot8xfgKMVtZyinmVCjMwKjh8kZpsLz@GKv48KEW26Jms@lK3NXc/93u70d/AhPtAzvgjOHUEFHYJU7fqjzGhFfMJurLgwcBB6@lqSck25/BMfckyr@TF@cWCfoherMd@obZeJB3XM3ocv@ahAWPwR7A9JdQ/KstIRDevdtSk5k481/xZOj4LwD7wbaC9OY0aOf3OBPEO9nFqmpLb0dp3zmwPlaVc2cySlY73xIQTvNu82tCPY66QSj6m0YGba6PAlmpOoiafXTlr9MfQhDfubKEiPCGKLFOz7A@n0QCFxX6sYBHMm7C7RV9r6xEgJ51jQntqwznXc0xCe@mCZtT644NpAWd1dJmDNRgds/jeh@860Byc7@H5HiSS3Kl0TzHz7djMQrIg@KlFM7/gF3iKcerOY9Bosx/kfS5aD9ybgN8jwZMJzq5zCFqNgF9eK8fv2Ke3eQ35If1VApp7yqZdAN@tHoy60@HhJdKPcvw@751Naig2QiLRdoN9AwzH3o@sTflNH0vVtWcEJapbTwmSCK4OnTvRW3aym9YUqrxoy1frx32HxcwzcTDNnC90X3sTAQBT6J0m/XQ6n1jYmAsoeJQPXX9zTKTA0/o0oi1DuGoRp@9vroBDQVd9t/WJZ@1@1JO@vTk7MdOkjlBYGc9AY9cx2q/ibsWbNImZTu9IKII8elREWzyVt@E8Y6EermpEYdS2nN4HiDfeWZzz8G2JCOybNPDcn1ekEXGrH/b@eN@Gizw@mzS4Pnz0c180ocVj@6xRbKKrbpxQMdaxTvKcgknVfn7ThuvxPeZwbINllS97B5dq9athvXg@r4JC5GIoH26hkPrZ5YC0WSZpz2nrX0EYO4iDRTG@X6HOheRSTUnD5HMIk9SYQcSrVvpzhwpdVVQDkEmBFhTkZlGW2gWxA90g6SxYYBX9@d048CaXeuWM5KQCz3qcXGDcLWG/aJnMP92bMrbBg0LPW3JIxzW/aHeWgj6rdsu6u0n/ignDHuFpaG3QN/J1q19ZTghJyoyMs35F6c5FOEbgZ8hv1Uyn/s5LsvRQCJq7iewAeX3fPTsgKfBPamxg89fsYtp3LzWeQRyUicAcppx7zztMCvqBFYV3GBjqEdxsyi8Uc/QOzqSp2yEqYhXaKcvKUjHuGJnAfyja8rNRzxjMHTlCVasdJvf7sKah38K1ciRdwxZy2Orb488UcXVNby7aUgQ1eJ3XzwGYvfjhePRq50oC0/eBdw6T9lJ4w2X/y642@yOGXJ4Wmw25GFF3QTSC8aRSGoJEX1SK6foKSsgbONGVqiAEm1QjkE4DT0wUNhu1jsz@NIazN@l@LOaAtB/I4d78S6@6n6SdmEVbWJO2s2CKC/agcl7pNBbdaLtH57sBxBBueqwRQOmm6q4db9Sxm8zp9sgCrlHxt4T4RA2GOn4MnVXuqhqGELJFL/FeKDpm4sV17hUTfJzVXeQGi4LKq0@kCLrv8ztACLNpXd75x3hw@VulrATvn@4Q7pLiwgKZjcNxu/trgwtVGl5o/N2Gid2CP6y2aQNfv8rRNGEfXQXQg6gk6NCbgLF1nXHp4tC3eKJb@djMy2UDO7eyBrXOPJeOahHg@hBafkBB/@R2KVi2wXmdiVD0uYNYcR3yERziFg6gS7txzxcK5oiknfe64/yMkxxDGG8T430ikmIaZptfYwG/3CvEGLIPvftCaXyrhCveqcwZP9C1MM/ZmrkjZXS1H@9mSrFC3zgLCKkNlzpbRnDaYbrNK5mwa3v8Rpq54LUXm6c2QtAMS/T9Q/4SKcl9pCxqArQCt/6YBEl5MA174SbTpn7QNa3QZwozuTCu57u7lhj2Vx2DewmceuYpAVMVGSpAdQxA3vRUw3cd0PEFMBmbVyVDtZQMCJOzrWMqcQNZhbpoyQZ3Fg8RwVWxI7ABK1yH1VQrEEqEUb2BzB@28Bn5i5LnnASHSpTwOmGakt1JM2rZAAk9HNggRxlk9VSKCkxlZdwYUomTNjUrM6s0wAUcIwUJWOuVjjNlwwmmOMD79aTKF@z5oYRlQgpOrytj73T5TsrZIcLlnL99GsY5GpjI75s7If4dTMO413ThzUAVGmhs56RKWwj18TC5zEXQOCpNliwiWwcRslnHbYXA@rWWbI4ccJ/HKoxnqQpuj50SEmVCW9u77xxn67gUWhw5nTKPjl8wei02GocZv3GabdPwQQepkb3JD4NTMcVhmsrlcAImCCPc9JyT5T602@hAz16CW1mA@jyPITbhR2inVkj4F7/zHmu2nKR2DiaUFB2yr1tRitQ2FAC8iRk22uOEw5@vPtE22MMENLsOCpiTIFSvXR405KllkJgobAgLIJjARMpygz45Mb2m3nIRC@PpjQWjW8Apd@d3d4Hn5xJVO9pp5YKjPEn8wx3DZ@@DO5phba4Kv9iXfuKWx7WoQ1/1zxfXy9fU8ykGRsShUAYcBAWXr4ROqFqIP7XYJtVhOlHP4wYndfGYd8gao2uZFvuaCPldh2AMTurzrROtt3414WQPJ7Art9RTUEyJZvCl/KNW1DHnZJlL3gUkn@VWCSyGE08EcUNLZQYbhyYicqkHckO7fsBwRhLJVi4ozX2IxI/A69I/28re77bR9FWakm5IaSTKMVlMzP7ne4k0oZZO9th85k3mt0E898vda8c6WiHLPmGoqV7m@Mh9XOXT1LJqAtd4HFklFfy0KCtZu3kQxPazr0LP8HYMH1fp5oh5mkzDGhpo4DJWcJjSPJ3BQVzwxNlm6syQKgvOYkL5nIMHiFRxVOZN9Es8HrwvsdM1vspmqSkxU0Kb/lb3zsaA9t7mx95HyhK7ySD5J7BaDl7L1/@MQizdsd4uS1yqvg98iLj/8RfZV8/TMQVzhMXP7UhVCNg8FKouCbNLjlTdZ6oGHG0AnvLTGXV/0GNLA8kAZgg8bYPcZLyK7eunYm3/SgBFjGRZaL4mmEnFhCJs3tFVnZ4M7B1hOjur/qZq5js3D7v7JEr489bSaqSli5rgaLfvFuvl5/XRd89wXC5LZfxs5zFnhllJXwU2mCx2p2XZk@InvBQGblK0Nyv46dGHJC@J/PTUXLCAM/SlPMSMgWWZf3Z7xhrp6DcOgZUNxXQN1H6qHfh1JNHTFvDbmKdtQ/eGnG5Su4ierWpKCywdmn4diBqptZaIMv/7xjkO0Ab7xSZ27NWHxIMO7UUzHhcOpuvCUL/UxsgetJYod/ZfyrHSeDCmtRMFPtqfUmDRM7fa73xSy4/tfhhbBPqAPVSeGAE/NeXpfLnlfkwtGLAhfWQ8vPFPlTtSg6Szq61YUZoaK8F5nSwp9ateh1VO0a9IVAuJqB3XfeH4M/pII7lA1OfEU7EMfWt8uTTphIbT9J60IplxDvVHq494dRYWGfrFaO6PtQaAvwwEs7hSp5F210QkFTT@C1uVVGf8/sGzM2dw7lJkjv7MHvOL985GMCR@tdf8SGSW76xxyIiOyD6gG/V0a@JRyX6g4SsN@z9h84i2CnVFR@JAASq@ypFboOEzJR0lFu@NqWUcKl0GkxpfuML9MoN73G4VlfU9aXx9juGvJSjm6JDmmVDpRwmjLYAEJ3P0F4nTTiVvzOsa781BVXOgC7nTHiP0NKbMMr2WryjsP/gs0wqBt9AI7eObmEuPk/sctRVh9J1Yq5Bpih8NKp7jsvg@bm85UnBLJKGMCRUnvoAo4rtItnaDf1Ot/uCkiShVgHx8CAAnKTgICA8kW7FydxU6tio1AuS9mTJpfRo@H/tz77lRFZYmbbMmqVIdbK82Dr5MgFBDtni1faeilXYN8UElasJIyH9i5227ib4R@LjkKR2chdr9/juq1PMMeQuLHgVXYJPhDy2a3G2WItF57FvNDjkRVyxY9/5ic5K6mzGzP5Zc79dpM5LETLW@juKlQrGACQrZnFK1xRxbGjhEwYoNZOrzk9jz0F5A7p6P7VaVq/m/m7Q@v4uhXUxBeXsrpJscl0@sxVJx8Aq0n2zlGERkaL/PGjP3tyOUHwW0kPDFGU2WjImyqicxQM9EXo9xAdBk8nNlOSMDzq@UI0U/FxjjdQvdvI4uyYtX2qXWXk8IdoB9ge36tFe@rMoii6wbn@BQ7Q9KY2SAxkWFmLIdf4IdI51GP@wbI1BEZPi2hqTPm8ovppI3HI3GhGvjoOYO@gmuaA07clJ/YNJVPs22lKaAP8EwWTdc342PnzNA1iqatirAkO2b6889NhPPYMvL9as/4j0z@6JjQomPiBqep8IrWJgSYvph4oUS6ft9USY/T3zpJ5HwQ6c4lNmCq/ZMffEWWqpvyyFsdyC8V7OBRxumZIF0PH10As3m7vNDwBCR5Nmm1j57binGz3iQzXLdbsuvhJ4hwgj9aFwyLtfKL4AK3uOEkGGKVgeT@EYL1cAcqC68gJkjt7H1C1nS9WiSNipT9l9J7cHauidYQrA1SM9m6SVMpoJPtNGr8THGzLLU2jx0WoNHAagq9Au4rDl9eHRTtzZEzwPCHJ9v2C@Pg7wa43GzZOqiUF/bqBCRW6PiZZjWoHSX@6jJD3qzkgyC39HEM/x3sn5RcpIvZoiWJ1FdSE7eqj/i7QdzTDXRDC163nkjztD@Kzo7EuK9IIIW7xFPa7IZLpnPbIoImO79pbeG4Tu/1VQhG5p2Uorzbs6XanGjpPkcLWfHLrQT38h8AbqDKZcU3MbUkdWA@qxGm08jw1JuOW2lxypYg98aKGL8OCWqa275O6MjACkhydqy0T/HSEF7Hof@Nl/GwT6IhiWptMI0kOzwygMjnLMJ6wlPW0XYHLL4XI0jcYr7kshfRqfj74zDyPii/ckX7O0WK0ykrFc/wRik3@e0EChUS7rWmo89WNNn89jHU@QI/K0zwJLq3Ren7UdoJ1UnoHwr2KVxVleoO9PwiC3Hac681kwYwbYxzuL2@tu5mYdeZEZyTHW86VEgUCjmv1RlvZcSfMs9Xp/lmw@dvWKirQWpgtJthDLYOlzcOjdzrp/mgrI0SgfI8WL33SC9iXsq/inthX/VBbkwzwPxaEC@qNSEyhRxI9o/NrlZ8haWRGsPT5p7wxboyd2l2CIQrZJQ@mJiharnjOArEj7piorA6C1UGdrGvjJpA@DAE9zdJVhWkzEZ@Y7V955AR0d@gptkbBkKV0ATF1frA8omcr7ZTMiBe7Y8vfO4fW3ou2YYTVl2yhm8EIdguzcJTQRWyDSPylacgmvxTZJDgHAuzfffr5Wc0fu2Ssp/oVC4qM9RopiCfJ/5eCAnuzn5z5pGVyMJyMQEDGrGwarG6P5zXiHmIvePpm6a45BXwnCEK/XjGzwvzfpicJkI90hyUJ49ED4ji6WFuDB3V0SuEICqdX1y9KrwN/m61c0AiZuQyIIeN0kzOiHrItYNyxYq2j6a5U8UWKs/kkdi@ZjKnlDnOome319OzYXmM06bFFkyWtXrjBTZQb6Vje4gO4MuL@MWFyVen7jF0znJDguIJUF4JRKlv6cupTsAqR8iPxoE@n0M2e3aWvGQwGDGT3GPcch/YNc4Eb/IcDVt7ggPkCqtPAsPCn9t04nSrySyAeZ53JrC46OllEfUSFb6JN2AT3XzPBw8fzqj@s0wTjH6RbA/FX2gZQ7i@1J0YnClJbxo0hcG/4l1cXmnA6mbuv7FZr1OraZ9QzeXxasdhyZTPzJkDAeNybbf@2BQzPE6feLOQyIg7g/4/t4wWL@5XE4Qa6f0sAs9Ybyh2bcrCkDlm2aS6VqmZd7ECvSArrzD2xpm09SKHOivnhbaPf@4InmA8QG74esHr9GS8S5w@Q/tjoow4cwjrWQmajHRhtdDq9BeAP3Fet5j1NcQCYnmTdyJ5tmzOMcYgUOPKANve7bys/y7wat5cBFYamHSPivF5GQSXLCoveuELJPvMLGsHDfOUfU45sV@ckyCSdB3wnvTTGFaJxuwJSelSUUbmYgAJnnxpxvkD9PJVTy9pdmXRn8QLMCd8BUbJztgo6nur3OLAYWPTcxzhO8E3WQeIke7LZw5qbNBIncfBHt4fotZTzF4YRm51usOcw/Y7rRFRH6G/iEpl6YrHOsoZiC6zWGwi4F@qB/t7pN4fJWT8rZE0vadco7Pzch4w@sAVAYVuYblUvlvG@Hulz@dUWqmbchrXKFOEFoIXoIjDVt4GdWTuD3Jg8Ov8X@HQTXdIvw5TF07oS@1WYcXNzfGdf0cXfI7GGMi8Ic8h3VYAYRSu5EWChraIzscMIDL6mNUC2K7AZUMrslmLApOxKzBsLozhqVPO6@wyDCzDB4/A5uwN5Cnco88ai6kFU1Mj5y16OZNXVdJ3GbKuCFVLrGCFO34faNKlIyZpp1udU3z8zXzKvhMv16D4oWW08@GzYthazas3Nwd1K7lha4XhHmpPpv4ZoqHngb@EoR4k@YArWZWdzLO22PapptaJt/AJfp8Ejtx0uMBm4gnP2MNSmQbIFCJYa4fFwVgsNRTHpJ6pcJqw3ZrgFAuadBAHM9X7lsXyidskjycSmBwveGYibVhjz6uSNqjOviUfQEItEZO3qr@3I969UKrHrTRwKIV/7as0UcGablcjEgW9XGgT37naje7TvclZH4Sr0g93gn0@jSTJUnyo5@UVwYwi8j9x/WoZkcB5pqgA8NLKj1J3EaOQm9CNZSk2tMom@nEqH6W0oTxAJWbx128jhUPZpGkAhsx9jtpBAxjn5ofaLbIj9gd2t2RqKgTNViupYuZscfEB@ScNgYJonZeLLl6/J5gkU9@3F0UCaXvG9DjW2LuKke9enPtocQOHTbIM0WNNDUYqEkAp1yx8@8qZJDRCpcnCzkfmv4vtX2MshPh63rqVGmK7bEKHu2MrXhY/0X1yH7PruPLDWvN5QtR3bZKWfDvsk@su0hOnAerNutvJdhctOZsJa47@06Csn1dkK6aMn9nmYw6GOsjBRS2dsBdVjeVbQZlWvYKjtcgr8knPxGXSmeL3YBVT9R02AsUHUc0Rk43WI5giHz/uubl1ggJcp4OgljqInio8Mi1GcqyOuISL/kE0rBvTtJk7eMKU7DqYwznfSWx77Arftrth3i4/ryeDXZoqBQOx0QWJxpmQVzsAgCd21BtZQV11IFSejxKTwXkZDdgIpFoGihly5JWIq/C3eOmwgdWiajYiswEzI0clIU8DooLuVD/PbsDr1@83x0gNeGE5Rw6/NnXXTBvD02sjdhHQbcuk6FqneoRedUDST6OZXFGcKorohlVRtgp@vMXv0yPW18rvFYgDA0s1iy0iq09u0fxZ6rJpaVXVGV@jPHUDthL9jeBYxk9PmEPz33HkbT1yZSflfjzLdjgYV4kRodGuWxkkru1@evhjdZ4oo16w7bQ55nSPV/e07ewwwf6fBMHIjGHQE4dKGrCGJIB8FVlupRQP/EGdykegKXLYf@SzJMuA3SNCbhUak5MFytGUBeV0jXuCCzk1VPry7s0ea@ls/6wa9rD8YvQSvau8142fZzLBQIQJSjhYWmcFWyw9aZyfXztz5D04oZq8fcZWrXkOR9Mbj8gH1nFZznrSoeIy2/NU7WeSQpcPwUbFX75GqKcFMD3d1x20iAD8MgGV9IU947T7uDX9wdYWlr2kJbiQ8xJFAkjG23WJpYnS0/1D9Z@WIaOKMF/QFkn8BeiUXDDIKh6RIyxETlv44LlM6OrycssZJYZhKAkOKpDDJXQX2lVaYIqN0XYDMKCatd4zmwZ9UbEkBGoeox0WaavCrrASk8Gra/Llxcro0Tl2bMZyFjQ7UAw4d/7XV0WY77o9zV@9CNXRdM8G@nzUwLzwBzFFmmffgeigByHDXFKPgGkQMWpfUEcPX4ArMayE7CkBuy2WF3KhPRJkTHRjNyy7E7nHUblcn/keHxVRVnXdll4RxcKoQVcw0wgm0PxxEi81unW1u0DPDB74zXUTA7hLxuMynwuuijX8UPYBKMcw1SZwD/MXLHscuvfG/GcwrdpsF5Ll3OOauxoQ7h5fwD2okRwoI6m5ZuA0KfFJ9gB3MWPu25FkcdxP5FLEnO7t9neYZ6eciaPPDKFPFswzOyBk8Iiz2Lv4zJGgW91x/xt9tU0Tra/zUG@WLUX1FC9nbs1Xh4E@@i/PGtqqUivdz8zRxecyZRcN69Vi3BxE@WQ0R6q2m3MV1TV9vfTV9tl5Fugpp/@QLEaYyn4sROymw4uoB8UhnRwOJoEohIVU4f7qUhBXhDUkbqgBbfVntqOtw1uP0xFfcNgC@i33qRWhCcBFCh3WMEcRz3K@IEDMdN8f@vBG4nLZGWOc6FZy3xTNPWBVyIHWzk10dLk0FMDGPeXwNhMSi9tiLQCs4TX/Fojj7wn3rvHEeOqtIKdZNMsJZBAQhfwSS8O3L7jEjvplK658VFnBMAEJXzc7RvJSabsCfxlZ8bVPXtCFHVGN@YTIQcQy3qdm/smOeThWLjEgzROtiX7lYgTIxBdnxiE5V/fqpjvICynpIdcDYwllqw@yofeeesYzLsmgzdClvSgh8tXgyeEgTf2Do4Sb1tJ@4GlX9tb9Jm7sE0pAv2tv/YLLmmcZjDiKauQ9aGSTAYbRHHr13/@ufEQyZrOTwvy@ZxgJEWbUaV2ApulLNj6QbjVz@Q1zO3OfKKWrgTXTsOVxAPU4VjF1Y0ozhJSSqszlXoUD8@LmHJgBssBamB9ENENo9270q4dtAKPeZ6WR2Kex3jUajP/EIEKIEpU5LEg1wW62@9zxWyixbyGuxwI2aLsQD7YNJ0kbCHYGaqfe@a0XLCkX9ggNnWuvtilB2lvXEBDAATx7SfUSp9MGrv80Cz1VefD4MOzolEJcfGeC2aLrMaiDNw3UyS8Hk6Nhl1SDV2Y5e8UxV/cF9lE2qTVMmasZUyYH5@2XjPsoGTPT4U@4/MsqFEnv5g0uFvYli@aYJ33iWJYrHgIy1XyCOR1maPseVclo77wc71jxaS0quxTJGzmDxL5dkZ4v9Hx4qKTcd6B6b104h4Xlv4s/0x6yfBKYbek7tfU@6DyC4vZrBWUVffh5gJwJciFDcUlz7PWur4lrCXPWIorAFBGJwDvhO/Uj0t692KTy0Y5rsbJmnil2G27wwcDRefv9hM@HjHOkRhTtySwIKfBpyzhHElyyV6UeXYGoU37N9omBf0SjDXBpo1g9djSazGrw8wN2kIYcgMB@QqRLS1uE9KgG1T0udkb4D4icxhbcf0KDQ9sxY55s@J9zrqu9RW/9Nfhj69lug2nV59mkKc9yPEnstPfXVrNpXyoFh9QCA8p6V248fX@D9uWDUWIULR8KlWo6/93cUW7qeNA9J2viCJVdZbshYSkUCQeEkLaQoFAk3K3q13JBAcnOE6wHcBI@@13TduH1frB8nhGZ86M7LElS1YL@Iqf27RNrQ7d@08PrHc9QXmdHLI2T6a4lO2Y7@CcRd3w1Js9ZJeHOL5mAV7MrvFqwFy/He0qtK/eTofxeN1E0CWISfz8bh1n2O28o3i@7WDrYX6J@xC@ut3wbanuBj50jj3vvecEXjgm03U5LZ4esd0XFFrbbWy7aMvPl8iHx/3YYd7Gjk6z4kAn1bLdMLve23zhz31U4GZtwbL5@WE5QeJfp9GLy29PDlQQ2U95p3vI6Bp1pAy9@IgHsTVIyPlahMF0Yz1n6Wrh06fQDhabWSiqn4/@ZuWevGq5fnxKPuSJjqcHVG6TcknDBLUHiPyRs9n43FnJceGLcC4Pt52hTlZ5LF9UARJ9@5gVTXpeYnHyRFU4Y7RLq3K56dSF99mOa5gOPO8Zf0Svkbfy6aBX7KLCW@Tnly@LdwL1VjJqKMm5AATWNZGghCLFoBHZIK5eqAATw0yBbQ@dvuk6w/6j6Q4tx@yajtF2esbvlpk1NBV5RcHFuNx17uy/gTvsGnd3tmG0glGJygApYjVDnAPIfzB4BvzLFa9JLkBidoeAILoXGCQK0FAgA@O/sLwpweU3BdxXwKqZ95d7MzZaWcVAruVUs4a2ZQSjPW@24HUSx5P125/5X2YNuUBdgAjggn0502uMqCSQQKqdIJFEYIYqquVcVaIm1T47pdD2pBGw1D4NieTatx1HTLt94qH0MtUgryETGmR7ReJTgLeRkKzi3wg3kclaVDXWsEpzvtNSqWip@RIJrALUTV3TVVC6JLpxox0YrRQKEJj6N6ucIt3kqB7d3xu//jGznKCRLnKR06Ap6x/iInSjJaqK8OGw3Lm3dP1f/etf)

The approach is similar to other answers :

1. Remove the suffix `"isoleucine"` from the original string
2. Replace each occurrencies of the following tokens with an uppercase letter in the range `A-U` :

   ```r
           TOKEN   REPLACEMENT
    phenylalanyl             A
   valylthreonyl             B
       isoleucyl             C
          leucyl             D
           valyl             E
        glutamyl             F
          alanyl             G
           lysyl             H
        threonyl             I
           seryl             J
          prolyl             K
          glycyl             L
        aspartyl             M
         arginyl             N
     asparaginyl             O
         tyrosyl             P
      glutaminyl             Q
      tryptophyl             R
        histidyl             S
       cysteinyl             T
       methionyl             U
   ```

   obtaining a string of 26610 characters
3. compress the string using the R builtin `memCompress(string,"xz")` obtaining a raw vector of length 12936 (bytes)
4. encode the vector to base64 (because I don't know a better way to store these bytes into the script) obtaining a string of 17248 characters

The code does exactly the opposite (from points 4 to 1) and prints the string to stdout. The TIO captures this outputs, save it to a file and compute the md5 hash to verify that is correct.

Note: we can't compute md5 directly on string because we need a package that is not installed on TIO.

- **saved 37 bytes thanks to J.Doe**

Comment: There are [only 20](http://www.math.utep.edu/Faculty/mleung/bioinformatics/aacodon.html) amino acids. I noticed you've got some that don't exist: valylthreon (really valyl + threonyl), phen (really just phenylalanyl), lyc (doesn't exist) and one extra isoleuc are in your code.

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes, some of them are "pairs", replacing them gave me some advantages in compression (e.g. phenylalanyl is repeated 672 times, so replacing the pair instead of replacing the 2 separatedly saves some bytes). But isoleuc repeated and lycyl are definitely leftovers of some tests, thanks for pointing it out ! :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that comment well. I mean that "phenylalanyl" is a single amino acid. They will always occur together. Confusingly, so is "alanyl", so replacement order matters!

Comment: @J.Doe : ah, so I can remove phenyl from the tokens, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>19851</s> 18639 bytes

<s>204 bytes code + 19647 bytes base64 data</s>
207 bytes code + 18432 bytes base64 data

```
for(;$c=bzuncompress(base64_decode("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"))[$i++];)echo[val,glutam,alan,lys,threon,ser,prol,glyc,leuc,isoleuc,aspart,argin,asparagin,tyros,glutamin,phen,tryptoph,histid,cystein,methion][ord($c)],$i<27598?yl:ine;
```

or, without the data:

```php
for(;$c=bzuncompress(base64_decode(""))[$i++];)echo[val,glutam,alan,lys,threon,ser,prol,glyc,leuc,isoleuc,aspart,argin,asparagin,tyros,glutamin,phen,tryptoph,histid,cystein,methion][ord($c)],$i<27598?yl:ine;
```

---

I took the words ordered by number of appearances (descending), replaced them with bytes 0..19 (`isoleucyl` and `isoleucine` share code `9`) followed by <s>`gzdeflate`</s> `gzcompress` and `base64_encode`. In PHP:

```php
echo base64_encode(bzcompress(strtr($o,[asparaginyl=>chr(12),glutaminyl=>chr(14),tryptophyl=>chr(16),cysteinyl=>chr(18),isoleucyl=>chr(9),methionyl=>chr(19),aspartyl=>chr(10),glutamyl=>chr(1),histidyl=>chr(17),threonyl=>chr(4),arginyl=>chr(11),tyrosyl=>chr(13),alanyl=>chr(2),glycyl=>chr(7),leucyl=>chr(8),phenyl=>chr(15),prolyl=>chr(6),lysyl=>chr(3),seryl=>chr(5),valyl=>chr(0),isoleucine=>chr(9)])));
```

Moving from A..T to 0..19 did not only save 4 bytes of code (`65=>`), but also 3 bytes of encoded data (with `gzdeflate`; I didn´t test again).

---

replacements, words and count:

```
 0 val          # 2414
 1 glutam       # 2324
 2 alan         # 2304
 3 lys          # 2199
 4 threon       # 2083
 5 ser          # 1910
 6 prol         # 1834
 7 glyc         # 1731
 8 leuc         # 1694
 9 isoleuc      # 1657+1
10 aspart       # 1430
11 argin        # 1405
12 asparagin    #  902
13 tyros        #  829
14 glutamin     #  724
15 phen         #  672
16 tryptoph     #  401
17 histid       #  391
18 cystein      #  356
19 methion      #  337
```

Comment: `18432` Bytes `bzcompress` against  `19647`  Bytes `gzdeflate` only for the base64 string if this help you

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>18409</s> 18403 bytes

(with no libraries)

```python
n=sum(95**i*(ord(v)-32)for i,v in enumerate(r'''~'W/P58:`Ote}|QRokHosM/W%~zh%Ab*ZI~i4?=Z/$_-Y*6D{ EGAP\ENvC,4=v$YQ#Z=<)e^5!p5*|K/Ap|.?CyO*51Ladt8c`it>w~1w2@{8.kb%;2n}Xvp8d{/GE4_c'8dO\)Qu(5G8[::X-(cMkgKeUli@0HJNa@Y84p^~:8'Jn #BoNyJn#5KAy[Lb} K{i=TlKzA^#EBWd>,|Ut!V.y5GCiXrO?~'dGYY;Pg6A|ub<ASiLi_@gL?Fb14=!x4-HE@4>3<_thTv&~8X%T2@;gaQy8Ao=DAnI50|7N6_lh=~7gF-@;CmFz:]?aBr~]K}eoFh{nG!4&:T>MSKxB6{N0TJ<ig@Md(ix?*\$;E0H5<f/M7EubRYLA1`A_Cuu0g"]!#w,Hf/uH2(a~~41\D.w"pg|{vO=.a)(xEqiW4/h7GIc3=vVKH[{7gTMpubkk5*YJ=b7Cn*MAmqsrTU%RE53E9{u^6@\FH&00={e2?EaeKu6>X3*B4g=b7'OW;p@2-+IoWPJVsg"`D-6yiwE)2Rd|"tM!|LVJ&gGLQGdv8WXAnT[me5~+$(~cJYxBx%UgO^^Eo|?fE/6~@wb`;7pw pHln{[PyjV}bfbbB`JBo$mt'@jiPZ.Rq"fpBe'IDiqCtV?JP80jZuxl#-,V&5oQ<.{/kn>bR!G;2sK#w8qXxQ-1VloKc+D5*EF3 qt*t9S\fq?^T54>\THI0#:l?guj}p&,yWNV1TZP^O.(BW8YK}?sD6IV"haFpfNZV>[CA<$tWVru5JiN+[j)KZyfg-axjd?E70,ae5(<)GR:9B?k0~ju#YoZb9CglDy<d9qSx\$5d[9scc8Bpc}X_NU^&K@- 0k* D'Pyy kI8&^:5=cTclE};`2r,^)&(t'f]^o-ZPHG"q^q;D^H[rFh1}O9qUEYWeg6F@y2!OwUnG2<)7qinEFJxa+%!b`yTu>oQOa+dhh{W4Ud"<FHl(r%Wjn>la[zgz"S:AubNNuYIjj*:FB1Aco.zjI~QHqy{93] Po^k3 yj/yL7'}lf24=R/`osaJHa9OF5%l*$MiBV=`=m_H=sJd/G)Ew2k-X|g$~E)s;s.R55x+6pmQIct0,ToJkoSu?D3@`O=cO+ZWg8FfsVhq?D^AB2|OzY~e;/9M~KDP)GMyC%v].1.u_'6A"y=|HE2h~GQjwW7j;1%KZ4fe8&x.{clSU'}rUsX+(q*mzzDtMwNZZa$c_a?SsIN*tA^{<Q\c'\(-M$&7douJ^@uhr##?|z\zoq$#POF|sbvI#*+IPeq<'EG'eTOhyd8M^i*|-h$aVa}.9r@\O6P-T<B!B<5d@r/|O](J8TW=Wjt=rS^H)qZ-la/"|" D49PxtBPmv;ir<:w7~x@jf[q_:z3e@p.+5/>)(NYqe]0#cP+7U<cglKWTR-JS4-;C_Ha#*N1IGV;,(GA5;9F<4ZJ0^u,]B{DNDIc{uu8<M\2~X3?`Ym7.ij%:86}8~!2w7oy8!#_k%/hQyn)DLBOqE7w]w8@d[lSE4:)w\'&*>#?b|ty2'z(!HNJ(oHkZ fTbR{WC^?]4wkPqT+&ka;XL(N?7*[{a$(@**GFl\4Do84*&DI\TL"HR:NKiXXtC(5?vYHm'g0J*w+(8?M4d:? L=|{2ld^@_M%;zz27JOVZU\Yr(~cmw>#dA!oQj*v`:Z6uO2Km,}gGYQ>" ;1$]'p[:s/z>_Dbj,}dET=B\/mq]+Iy/8[^PXQz7M~^30l[|E-{SPi^>wJ2D^[fU#[("yZ:ij-V>T{Etro9={/4As$tUe#4e"nqBkE%:~Q/%[&Q?#8$9[v6!I9:m#a]hP;'CuO2bj|8W:DNle/H[ra;o(;9>a-AJ4<Y2W1j{fP2*a?6EAR@hc!Z=&Ai]7vTN geg.rd4Mru|2u1t?5# DK19#:B}~EB9-]*Uo igH$;AO!6PZ=:^Ug{1M-M"im}jmezk,.P*KeD_3H*|]',?c412GLa;qa5#[tsjjRVGyT[5 tY-QGc2QjZs/5Z>g+=,:NG ccTmgW9<&Q3kma$FPec(=}h:NlHWh"x;Y9"&~y2l6RWq*Gc`28!+D$hnK5=Lto4.X*G&LCq0JNZJoC-l2!n9B#A&=kPjuz2C3CVXIW{v7d6zy!/%|dt:x^i^*f=]+~r!U8P{ejrlN6ktBm+ViU)d3Of.]&xRKtlOi!gQLKtms<g;\&-'rUU!@M4dq(3J``&vX)#:]"qbCtp@S<?~y]vxSp.u9F\FyOq3=xXd*X|]JP-[08{*>ek,Cd;-Mi;Jj~U~hCI&^i]BrP`yr{O76FCP=n_R>h!(hXb>ZTx\.qqbVD>#kx;*Pp%7BxUrV7'M,;/cJ&pD/pVu+!){ft.MV|d2Dzq;^aA.I$,NuCKMCS|BGVNup_4F0)f~/{wzL9789F.d{IZ+ E?}g1d{ne [>~uB#S<.6H#'[OAvg^O,P-_OHai]oHjf].s2KCWd Va$3Bp5NA~HN1y"@h6F5wuPi\'-AG-T!#j=i.Z'cp'7gv=l|Rf:=QIJi29j1T h)?QB=n2Q7*z]cF#6':^85Cd[RIl{8.Xx~')EvtuIP#kfy_WoxE3,iwd$;<yP4o>1()MhfY-?"bm/PORKI~,X\'ry.Pr#7;nOnzCfa)NCv*T~a1"~#w"ZBb<@xy-|GH=a-cL5 X ZeWEss8Vvv|ZBqZ"l&wAk`@R?P]E,N$O6"n=,M_{E#{2k]xo"d.&w i_q!1Lz0o=0OYs5Xo<S"R,joLW<Sxqu`'aZrq?rWsQ2/C&A*Lknz#x$;+nHbKX.KsC>1)P98s@=3D!{,MBy~9Z1(t,Hj\nJR%/ft,#OkTMCD-8t0^R^&k[~evH@sAr)E'L[,LJ8Q]&K:$C#}qE`nH;m:A79M&HpG%V1'OhbL#m/j:mtR\L[6mN=Wb>d,l Z=sADm4A\roI'Sk0UaW=#3[tx.U{Ms)G^[!\Vc|8AL.=,4MK##F/4!EmuXM8+|ppYpzE@ 6YzOdtxl*snP4Ct7wUWYYmH`f`jplhw^O&@gWBN@BTJHY&DyZvvYM@?kk].z}6,k<`REY{>pOCIy"%Wpi9_i'G-<9$=#}T,h3X<[{{**!OEeBn+*mWM9A<>,A(8By rz](GI=a(_t.8M6R#>t!Btvq7Zy]G:-x)BCc9Od6bR"VK^<-k!KYlrcdp9P!%Zs33p~4o}\bb\_{ d'oq{/no-0+b[5%:HCTgnWe=5v0d6hX23:6/5@vHw_(r/'uDu\Bp4%hS:OcX8x 4_fi*zeB8?k(iWQ^y_(nhx"b: =_}Fb.!|<F9cokSKbcm2CGgZHh/mh0OjWiptM3c7.v;.>:.BMc"D),[a;8[GB>c3dC1E-/Nt,8bfw"ybs"=r!Tjx'!I#V|5k}Xm!+"AN1f1?,XwU{6jiWb6D?MyOGSb2j pkIUz!eMj&MswS!kxt`~wG"~((:14tBFI/oEkqtpp9#b8_V4/V_^E_jc^@JS1PC_'Z$mM2iu=-fi}WC=T-Q}Q@/|!Hs_{wAd#Yd&Cc(!_ )a~iMFUU &s2[&n<0N!ni?/QY{:m;{.,9,PB]js<q@(cPL9M+qgk/@CwNQQj^"F:1 x-~15A$d-"xy$3$Jh"eJv',%V_j$w1u =8^{ITa;/{ht9U0|}RH0?1YdhM=b wrDo`H;z\bZ+FU]m03gK+/ltk)5H,hnOcmvKnW%FPO=FbO%wFf(]y!`#@]3=)A@?!|zLl~GQS{9{A+J2N:<4BaZ5Rd F**Vd5$QHgCUhE01,O!l.jf`~d\r>ratuneztP*OxS>$*Lo9vFe_CR&IErniM/VR*~=UwqgZ1oY0Zq($koaM0*ACn<bh|Zs8cG`XMAV*j#EI>+b}uA3E%.#]8U$p-3#P5%lg=#n@?]%H/`"c\`~p]5:I+iK'La(LIkhWDW~FF1*VwxzHd*a0gpL"ZwjWu59^LgBYBZ\)mT-2I-gNC#yrqY0),[^=^:1["e*pt\i3zplubVY7jr0p}ea?<~-IzA^jb$YWYO)<!WCJyCK'o1=1=_ sIfk/|7?uZ~<LhGtrXEH"3aM1RrL58UPbc,,NhFHTZ&%U~4A}W[C-tx55AdcJ?~E7%fG.nJ&#2c,#.${:F1ZHFcVd<!9UE`Dx^*q`S_}w34;d3K6=Pqd{V5arXF9z3vva{,AV2pttVV$)D^.%"`ZN'(yvxCZ0^I:W7\TOg|2)nr`\WG_CVpJN5-Tmt*gF#|/;v*@Gm!:U81diKU&Be;6R(N(@RcpuD~y3d(+tPI$xM^$&<"%WTP4K46Cy=}y@rzP.c@.LA5.@v+wC 3,5->Bg'2A{QL@yXi#|\\>!,IKA;CY+~w%4~SnY6`tM=ySey1hjCe?N~`,nxwEXZ?B5k\g"1i;Me^)dV=iS-;aM9nD5:%,_CsO:NnZ?(_qjZXPSTbE}45|fvs,{2-fmKm)oN|/nGG|Ajk7}T=f.'95B@QFR.]h<CfRsKsN;b1!0%i3zj4{5'|~8\o.3TcabH6i6XD{G d9y*\[:o^(cI6{DBoixs7p`lq]j,Gy>qb/=mH~5`]]^wMs.7#9*P*sj}(\:2qCc,3ialk=;?be7LE2!S<'68s<nPXu(_aXdo9f5jN!#2B[,>,DAB35k>VVIm{U@?'ke1F|U:p07NO*h.*rb,G-qCEn(70ojniIlKg,<VK}8$wa&>AqE"VL}5"B hLRKELQ|~8,'sxF$sI.3z+gurn0N"K]>_qK[2/ dnX99T>]lc1AE[EA^u%od,l%j\bO^$\kz5P.6OnnzLv|A3.8YY&L2I^a[=Emogzs~a[kVnx~/]K]mzC]Lx/#kkkVj{S4drJ-M>EZ{a@-+=><*1>";<[BZS{2EzW#xh8$wLZAN9>^&K;<;t=F|%2+aZZy'.1#%Ncw8V8>]&FE/;a<0wuZa.WJ%GTOWC!`Q^YKmgKJK%m}'.l:<$Gvjm*ED&LsY4-PZ/\nD`h,@Bfh|'&En;qe@TL!]Ks|G#.)n~Xto6GT{*02^WVvw[?s3#U7}uD}wA"<n@[Qgs-vOOu+%7Jl;Ph5tgF3lUwOS7xmCa??B:g3:CW lrjmH`-}j60A_xl)k[!2\2br3*\])# &asbz-|;uEYHUyo(hiv]+TUs2YBXC}Pn_>WftsZFh/`)hR~l@'W'xvLmh{<MBQ)P{zUM`8He$|`WTUfcVIXxr>,\*ldRT\56E`#OC]`.u*;\`_Gpq%i_<*?a SQ:(WKojXHL=ltohR`g?MGz;!F\t'cU+3lb&@uKLYyzJ-RzYKKcO4\8ij9fa}y%MjQ(d:viR9N(V6y0[=r@rR$9I-DfLOddn-1RxW>bcZgUF$Z51C7%g&0;\4#;OEO2p=My|8])3vxk~!_NLvJC[D<4X|v=$~2!FLZ.*R:u*a9;+#\s.Lm=4'8+"MoZxGu#xnx'ld:TX,3|Ar+QY0d?rQV,1@|!YJ=|S}TzS0aYCf4;hce}}S:cGs!yr*Jhya3\tSHK{3JJaKb-(?_z7]p{C]Oo)+~U6;L*8t{@<#,x9h@,\2Q!%e{cerzZuP:d#cZ6@$yqi`%MU2e; /(zKXGT=B8{~L:(mw?C]4wf)A"AqdZQvTIh\\<7:VBp0'9IQP0]Hz"?_,LJLv}iIWz8{k8q/R]s:g&d0Z0=>aa#D5p5USbpA 5 &Pe1|uaR~VMamMV#8CDE,unJMNOYC3rXnZySA,@tf+s9PV;`GK.0s@iv7i7(M/<q>NvSV>X1w`5b83C-2IwC6nblw@NAN/vI:?q,T?qQhk'<AfB\IL_phJXk-qG}L'P/^i]X*'7!~kS^!uBCD.?a_[:$K!sUB*+LMW:kEDxY)YjL#ohefM9>:o2O9K$,uH^zz?p( !Ep5G*cQe2Q1{&\-;Y8;G0W9+mlD&Z"D 87Q<5H~J[+Hq.Nk41v{C,U?1Pg]kZi 8U:g!K@t @k0rqq44Ptu}Ye}<k8{Hbz7>:rp@NIB%;be&t<h}AO~W]7uG@IX']](|W2_U)TqDGTBQ'Ap`a;@UB!I.65CN[m$lSLl9cSh=`7D0bp#^3/Lc=vF#g.kbkP""g@PKSX4K2a8-r'Dp%$"mQ,Dz1f?;ob'4*9G(Ew!wF:RL%|TCO>csigdhL"`2o'h\plI64r(cv4[1mz+EGF1*|z6Oxvpi:p:.~|!Qm<:,{,^[/tjm,*5k`xr1LPU6VJ6*%{[Iq;+1vdDyahWoD0DcV@|\^$Se-G~5"2!JAiMd7*K/,>b+P?wPvBzya1zj;@NwO;ctV$s-LXxf#<T" Ag/{E*{)2g9gn.Hz<ZQCITusb0$+v-!DNO,Ad0X-8^A\!OE.a&tCVDFg-:lfS$c4-9~0Yl|h$VIhN{uA8(YjfRx1&!0{69SXy]@#QCa{@bZC`"*<ZLI.W,(>hr1D>qvR7Eq.Pvarvh4gSfg6Z,|6^1/Sue|;S[sz*9;O3,*=%rsN{Ex0g+Z&1B8NX\4y"FEnQ.H[bHwe`PH&mn^pV/KG NO'6fVkHG ';Q:sv$Q#w'>oC``;aL.Kz8CmGVe;erD-vIJD8-y%c`f;+e<";]by?TH,')n/wIY/V)8S^56&uq*[xvJRWkKvs#j77G(ESZJ#?oLBk^-YMBi"w(7+M`4Jey,/?-mVeqGtz+tsy7uza`'_mLQ*!&E.U9#:["cCUxQS<]uh8&\BX7(_n17a?YA].^k4qBJB{I|Je_0\TTl_SRXTnRW'jCVRsM:]`!6'  %8H@Z8a^KE$YH]Rls_9CAWHJUv8 `YZ0$NgG'O~^kkQR{X~Nm]%8C0eH(.3U{+QdzF;97>K/p?sm7B7<V~l6JdbsN^[U[v$ FOZ1Ts,L.d@w#6@KLZJnVe:m5 E. JsmPMBEKfXI>hRz:O'3vhP 2o4+S\d]:`:U`D@aD2F;<^fj7I|pLd(h/G^tV!N?=LlrKmaX>*NRchlLA2vEs++g.uI](Y2RQAr:,>S4&%Y-jZ`)e$/B(}Xgvt+qv~+?xXg3gWWZ\F?2M%UM@$7(85QEW,;i]$!C(taaMec1@r]1m[Jm=D)`6zkxUw<W|@%Rip'H P"2O!BNqMh:. '9lS!PMZX1-!j,cu;uV6#'6MtMG|x6Er;l2gNm[Y[Q9;u8K^\2MU[=m \v@'Bh8ZW!8\>Y&x;/.S1[%6O1H`*1_LmNi|r4<&)wv8.KgW-u^{]7zfgH>hb!hG#>N028;.j;PhdxNiG[_EN>e^tY:&*Bcq,,!'\?}Fy+'sR*o;qq"m"uIS#P{3itm*S.3w@ks&1!/>>akBJQAXl~d4_*m-7u*_`4JvPy3DYlr7g+=Y.~JEi>JES(5a\a>7.m3LxFBW-NsnX,etcd/2  *_Pg/U>@9fT@#|RFb2Dl,J:-K?6{L,zlcX3~N%DSZQ%.LG:\5*Itw_4}@htw3eFrUs/0dvnS|<?MVAX$C.8^iIB:V,*iLO/cG_kSue>:R~hZCT+287BFh[b9@=ijYm^cS_xT!8KmGQAVyBL|_'06\Eui%VL"C<u~NhyyY'ISHC'=]=r:v(?W!xOc`1nfZG=3R]\Dxq`_?Efgd"y05O.5wTC`rx8NsA-lb:&{i9|j,!5NrDbQ{Y=rOA:cOC3E$I)ZX]u?RMvnv`1g6S#SIRD]GJ&X><sB-L(mS^*Qop22R[C43'`M%*pPJr&{~vz5b\qI*+#xUpiYh&Qnej"~)`e<v?S#vwO^R3=Y/LMO"<Qw=2W }\@h{G07XWJs[^|ujS1t?e|5;fztaDgfl=(!VLzQ,0YJv !|s;Ihm0C:#\z<pS3"|%NL"bAo5lR:42ut`Q/F0Ud}F,'"7dl"Cmb!HKkq&suhMee;~[7rkwy>Z,x.~iGLrb,!vINadqQoLA+A1f/fBMksw4\[B-]H:`R0)NWm$sAgimDIo~&GFx@K#a(O|-(HJ@%0D@^a/4QYV3eO9h!|5G9.NijhgZJ!=hjKVuiNF\vty_sWjqU p+.^9Op:uLpU:11I>Pg%W3){Z6h}%q/|^>b-:DFi3tatgrwsKb}Vd#)JC#eY+?d7=PB_XXR/iPC,%$w/HS5jbVH30R%hWoi>jQWQ*Mo_nm?BX:z>+,b<UX9=Muwb%mC#}qKYj=S](#|)/s&^~Ps(/Lk][._HRh8N!N=u3rz8D@d&2<h,!WJ+Fv3SZheC&Z.dN$F%8]kmjbxGQo>}#EfUp]0y?u&zS9eIVKxp}E ojpEPz1"$OOxCNOa0?T@:~zBzn`sK*.T:s~q7`e3,\)/^)XNSex+@T9rx:l{tb/a`%0}BKA>LM`B:qJ5<}26GThpIV8"Afi6v3z!~~*ur_iwkcu\c)7Bu6Q=FO<BP0Pw%ZXzzqKn4*;,bcTuJG1<ZVm8g*05ApaStn8B5CfpIAiz[Aq{5]^&o%?o6Mf^Re';Bj8z#p>|DPt^u,8!T7$uPHvq#s-bMebl:R|%w)]aNxI^'Uw/R*G\i4^:k5+7&@}Nfi$9Y"p}EQ2*uQD!63{bjbBR[(:f~ePB/EUH!}-&l]<W}"2c6<FObUYw ~Pn^P!9<]'TmwBRZZ[!]VZHh=C@*K_yW;u|P7B;yV7kGC+X[t2c>STk7%%4Ot35?;u2&[6B OUvbzmr+_{(R@gShda<QA2cPHKveK9_Lm$|'=Zzo]'m4\0Mefm0dYa7"Q;eQ"Sjp\!Da@G4k#=,@OPzuB(Wz^{<B&Fi0yl/W_5R&i*tO+xm}^c0ajC&ngdPj2#:I/#=XJ6Y!ViV[N!q;h,khSFix?|1]N0J=7'T76c_gpCu`$b6E+v:6DZz!aH1zt(1tP:xYb~'Gj8]veI{zkf$X{QH(.]Q1h\eEO&?Gdmc,\}v`H20,WW-Cr,}X}2]+f&pdrVKKBk0x0Y\/'YQ"X*Gt;]*B*!*,y%N.rz[b^,(yO{\UVJNXni>$T5lL0}T5+|Z1J"0;\;E&'x<%tC,wVe'<> PODeq_ny5\.K!qpN!.$46t d?\H`l%NldfL@1a^fy3mSeQ6{BRd;(?%s_{TbfX1@xGeupV4/K20gehEX~8X~`}_Fm}w"lF[;pF~YyDP?0;-*&y(:k9ro.n61d=OPTVT_.TR3Nz%_-YK4kD/^^'CMr=EJ(30<{C*[l}Si<0QuD!_}RY#~g{VE6]72nxK6=aJ[8LK$HnI3'J`y6K[s>uD8+4[KRsw*;|OK|re3H/gQgZ4;UMzeV+~oM2.HTn@2d-%73i'UB%-;Mn/{pMMevaHv@}j5|/.ie>m|bw?4ddXyN@,6zfVe"TxVjP+Q!`TPDM#p+F3</DKbPv2QMc)~3b\d<e`H!0xDw}p|@:S\W)ROuipuv@"&2bV8D}o6C=297#)s-Mm-n,toL""0l$^<BGWX@<ya%@l+dRTF)eZ5l{w/W!VtJ79D,{^55ygGagSMxF</De<Y_n?Qu#gO7D&:qXr%S|m'rZ&V)Hv,`Xpy{H;y9CZuk7]62m@JLAP%T0CEX*9@}13ZJN]TvW<)$(\ [ Mz$'fC!'dB(1"Cz;Y-RIHSZ&6_N@UeOeU4rR>w7irW'C#Kcj>K2J$5%)@O5hCh2[S`5E#Rum/.0Os {YI<C{(Mk?z;ON(p-3dJj,dR1-,jQdDPF5/AzN>-ZYG%|A 'Bh}TJ?*$uI2Z|,hM`C_HqlAA=s#}%bW$"}U}QEx.LV/GX-*wY>ZbuSi]?}(Nq{y/f3c4<{G5M;.JsGVY%rY$)%K>D~*5E+{@nAR$S+6{|yK|EcV$yu&gikcQ''}9]t?P}_|Xgwbu~ys5|& GN$X{p"mO.w &?h}R .wOFU",r3hmHwABK"8\'xC~(OD%t_d5#!J{5JsNU[J?$<Nu1~B|mi`s(;"~WOZ{7> 52p80Zwzyq;*hn~dp<t[SHm^`H9OcfyV$;t<'Wi$F-!ioQzOmev@i6:.nNrSQqQv%tS|V93q3a\?iTac;*R_~m~'LpzP0,)Ng\33yQ0ZI7(L6vXAXD#'DlD.8V.73VIl\T}gF3&FD-a6FU6K8FIZI"}fG)Nk"*b,nKW&JQ~OUP1I+w/h2_yU7f"wK/@r.8~m.qtbZ wP;J9K;c++C0&:J%ccfGFV-_[G<I|Wx|Mz+ 'v:ch]%fODW2LSH.J6C"W-$9)heW;/GH*<ZWr$UWM"DJU`4IllUaQ|"?#Wvsse-I]CH/AFI)d&{RYH:.Cn-WGah0U2^2RAR,-j91EdGQss*\jK:Fj#e_%))g;<g$W TPOkv(#H~c+u>zWECzZ]pC%x?Q HKvQ.FX.'~$5*0DAL*8gzXGlG<|tB b&D\Z)whgNhMP8pQ{P^v|edwyFCDK+i0)Abn/0@:.#y{;bCN~[um ;3<|6* |cA_S:sosROm1>Ob30p'\T'=5:>B<[7.>z@=\AD>dS`cQpLa^H;{A~E6gTZXRWu;e)/7jUNA}n${48TKYIz[tO'{EyzX!|w|<dl.mPt[s.ykT7C18%,Kurh/&HqR=8p*3{$X-HEU6naPv&R2-$84D5>o6tTZ8Z=W2L%1d @G}h .4[KS`h wkN%ODDt~X_dK4PC%B']6D6M6V]{tZk^u`7q=:4BFtZ8q+^>s@ I5&.|Jk?p>`!t|mNZoE,%wLr+SQmRrSWo5KIN{>+@<gH[z9imD9V^I3ZJl(9i|^*4J^}]U/.~SNza3+ wO9xbL<o54+%~~`.D?\?5iB01!rZq=[ ZgB1PIAOU)MrO}`yQHc\O~.a0h=d5"^NI HI6u_1U(yb~v_FK^%5C(1LG`UMg"Eo~@jrOTF9vLhL~#<3_<j}bzLKD6u/{/C?cT?:PB'fgnn;&d9=T8?j{dA"jSLDI2AvReMnh=B<NCkCU[ PtCTp_G\:5=$_gp8!A6P(,Y N3+@8v*]-?r+^p:{RLSWCA\~="'vbROXh&K~3(4DnLr~JCHG5$snK8WwQ/<D90&7n^fgc8_#6[3`D.OphAX;5k]2>k6@=j0&v,ZY|^P\g**es+b@tl*dUzX;u_\Sad+7#4V3xf2&[vb'8-GZNS2 El9q>(yY7:,iF*".!<us*Pb[K@}30+&&TG=8?rqY m;?e#=Ggi|8="!8@<3*H}\g#ATW&KfH `=WJ#V)&c#] ;Gp<&9-5y.Zz0o|[XR>P2]5C}Z_)g(<XH!Ra6>vGd`5msAWpx-m7XTY}0t+9W>s}4~aO&Wm%B"(9v4+@Mb6b/Kidx|iO`xTLYy}%ESx?6k1CO8>VWOIY4I42u5}Xw/j&]<,H$=/.R6h|0D=5>OQDo]ntuhOgZ(mc}Y%PR4C'4+5A_'\'A(@)5HJLvW|rtrNiuCuNOjVW+FF;e^]i&m/3o0ep|R'/U&#xEG0)p_+x'[K6NfS!`>NK5%^Qm7rb9!lPOm]E>[e;ch^OvL[m2}P|'_"#!laGM4d2VF]-=JcJ:eUm:>f4-`iHrx{*v|VTNOr_#rII{}j$@K0.uPU%x+'8b2ui+6239OtaF8&J|&7Lb@CWj+`gJ<t^.<~/v/IwuXnwUM&O4j/FVGG%\P0_SFwN\4qoE-]YcW,2ml;So]P/7o_FNZZR<i2$#Oi`\OhSx:tISE!6n/KeYGqbaPEFx_I3"wWbAoUkx+0R$)C) 34GOZx2x6d|<Wf Z4;"%Dr9oZxaIJv-ii$yOug~V|leOe<5*:d>EnZREh1\Upub42{.a]<&s-isg\0>TkwF&U \.Be"'tXt-k*Xx?"O8;t.Kk\<#gank&!1IozlTghZWrj<gNYPa+Zpr|^3Ss/59#O=prD9AdfrWvyLKYKl d|17$kPz]C]$K03S<CHLTfPV +e2j,nwZk8_x~eqdf/'O32_D&vRKO<^ODUD(.jYw=sjve2'Qc8Fr4#D)_#k<E$X4NyXx%mDAV3(^4'#~G1.g|wo>aT/w^CC)*d3)x2bubQbn>JonC!NS=Z-]q#g+8Dy8.&"L{KF_'a-h_&hM~} x3)HnwF6V$eFQTjbXSO?u~'Lw4rC+MZ1EpZ>i%AcoMOEl{!BG n5fK-O}A|_3k(q)YZ;iTTIzHh2q{r1Iw50V}%_1iSWgAVa#06#U-'2')V,oznU^#KXf-&jmXb0#<O+mkoZF%Mrc Sm=),w1V],9\JXSv~M_zSZG|_20`Je.](!L5I0SV>q#2+?Lqe|_ou3jnR=Y/PV }$u:j:GSo2>0'p*(qX8GXI?KN0Z]Vv2h*;@7v|L,U[="he8boXyE~%pJ#:+*P!ur;WhW(>7O] ci9T[cwPiv<L2uiY6z9Zh/0@F*9E"/8yb(q;:4&%s]~ie_Fjxb%~dR;s[9pvZZE>ECGD$!(_zQg:+*%=!5pk8^DMg`@y:;;hF38xJ*\kOni+HYf8B_@!#T]3UP<_s/@aK$M{:?0{g;\TM4U~yr!g;3F+PbgCW`[aKt?kAfh]:L:~m|C&^Y})C1OTnp 6waM^o|eWCl>_*&G=RDf{#}COC+T!<X8'=zqf\m'@gr#7hp"M/d3M@Ap2Iu}.!0MF;E}sz8\R]x?c_`~T>"MAK]Zmc^xx(*+Ed<0tF2mRa~yu;IdPmc,fg#Zcp+AF(k%4gr3f1gs`fDt?>r!3;\5L[$zL*)g`}"6fwK mP`%CD|W]=+V53g<4URck~%Ef>f]dcE-":l6&)]eY]"vxA\:?!\$L#mOn2idtd;vo*u=d|!jMUBo__Uy(YwSFE^\8$z?(Bb)37(DlB\3~$hGOB&T8YecOel$=R yxT9@O5-XVpth*fXL+88}}zeH<}d&:6Dn*@z7<~4fmNIT|97{]f_P*U<6Cnx1~Z2lE|B;`<uIxxV< 8@pw}];S+A pp7f"2d2DH#@dn^@Ia?gCK$5 MZ)th"z`cV#bCz/d'Z &MD,HufENZb"V!L$Xve)C0dn(=zzcdrfP\3Q(^F< QE;<\L:Xy70Wg?k"2j:z7/{9%(o nVc2,kOt{DHMh(L{+hRy!^5$k9VuD:+<Jr,.b%^p+h+~L3Ke'a{P_jd1Kqo+n(_*MD?E}d=}*2H@#"m@onl5BF 3>`u*%ww,Xo13SD86r>&/%;|`OOLaM5wQ+f+A*2?xA^iQe @]Md,fi"G>}CtgsP[2VYP69*hXPVHap:/O20%yg60E\7aFAwt0vUU=c9:.iKID'6.WF8:J*Q#{-umBvzq`!(#. ]z\7sclqq*mTQy&6*/|Z:q{_8C;:!-p]mqm&XKne|v9v{g<e7d!o|4"hlp,{BgH-`pV=V$k.n|~#`Yk/\/KCAG<4;GhUZb\pd_wz}z+{v&\Cup8O~n*qgFu!4V'XEBhMf*gm7x-AnWfA.6S!7&X$&B;zdDob2 kzHGgur;q:}E!NQt cj]diJ'g/IXk@*}160=>zqXm.jUQ`^EZN/'uUIh&6\R:z!vP`XhD27gzEn{~<TGP^Xweg2V&oMdFVG.l>i&cHnA85wr6S(K)U7udBEONUnTk='6a&9hyVa>Z,wQz 1FT :IA/3n$ 0mozt[xl$XJ69-kT[+ 14cCpTl]TR=QqkE 9o_czE6]D64ApY@H ~;TTEhc#eSW{_bO.HJ-qe|P2c)[PX|gIeIyJH4HYFrj55pQY"D^< HQ2nx/&_43Z]W=<$ 7ciOkTWr7rCDU{z{er(7:/I|T)bH(pRBLaVSu ?&vh$Ge%rA>O^yJm5u5fAqjI+Q'j7C{=q\@XFn}T\{8#BYHa}eHWh*Npl$9>OZ.^0q2d}lyl^zL'%A7pHw1@FjE\S~K$N8O%mq"MBrB,fAYN"_|:bpu*f<&+wSev'_c30>Oyh`HQ/s+{-{pbhMY8-tE"N@z{m=wx`H5|y2D(*_r0,Y>udqIdsr][+=zLq#w`Eo-xLjhlxVuQ0rk3[ugW!G~@}j%zQ)xHmT+Q*Z|;g}@NlV[LkO7zwU|Ov!P7h|aYHRRF@kK^X/8S2staUS|UR=dSjS]j@{-H~t|SB#J-b0-@|?AW^![5e[(KYX,s%TZ OVasreul-Rfv,i080@k:glb1W2W3Xc*JjafH9$QU~<td3'1m>hWja`w8Aav^.{|s_\UCqbz<4/)[80D\ijM#I?_^e;L?]7>{l`W8-W jTPP7UV?B]fnXhhJz|I?o;9L1ZVGTorHC-ll@=OfcchbABF\8#oT8u=t;]-Hcv/|M;|XOMA"&k83N8g%y{.uNw5@%n$F5IpVXi(qJ#Hy`4r[f8%>ul-@OI%!N?ndsAUx|=~"u-,zOE}%xGSV1wndi6 m4tcRi7hty4@YXIZQ2 ",#"Cd`}';}T" O6a.a@Yl/e'<04(_M}kze{AJ7]1#[S~D^ur.:os.@'E$vOt%^'~P<^d\&CKi(|XX=7Lah<E]FA;`]:H&<7D]}'NJ<Q~)5\m0"Z:*~Vn\q\id(!_PaGseR';q~,Ifm3YP/9|+bH(RDZuPMk[S*iK"&]_g}X'<3kaOtVk4,ud0J&U?FgRIL>D>!OU8nb?Igf(XVZ$%yi7o].1vAKaB7(b6FDfrB{2,k4CaPSY)-Jw@2sH[YBX;%sMY'yqSGL~YiODLTir[$-ydu9kK>PeKCBl)"'oW%:nj1Ia($6*{/C"W>wozYw'0]$tOk8CLc9E:A}5\!t*$M&Cb~ps{Hx3ro&>2O&Gp&D}|NGXh$AG/W(:3CvZTwa`"2]/knd?Gb7r-%(,T|:.>T].&h4CI;2rlR{i':H5omu0uAb%Lc'v|eYw2c-6:nvY?#ri&vvKR{{g+UEN,\WGI3'p-i9`}MjGQzg^_(Nh\,{hmQl6b;g'kM~: R|-&Ue(}|)8YR0\46~-E)8Y2[\iI9ssX4"\m_de[l=}DT(hvFud<ItmjJgL_--7'EZx}|)\3'k{d*C[u7%FgPj[!Z0AFpK0s~Pc^!yRT0([_'!B6UgrOEhK< %Y/_B9S1l21H"6-tA7FBQl\ZNqP<3}QHY,1]-{5"dDI>n/@2Yg86nx[H`cEq+JL\)4`]XQhjCuCT~]`q~)o,(O?CC5@<%is=s"LBh+nIq Ao+AiGS0Hm}?E+;W.I%j`j!Dko>I^\|~.T97m7k?z7qff};vkS~QrB+{ D)x<(s5(M1)r[~_#sDLV>`(H354k((!Wh4:~y6t#/8E4?Y1FdJg,"_@Vf^T(7Tdgsv2:6FQo!O?H=+y-ehph- QY(8DlK\xe;Yx?~a`t^xX($qST(_b4qx'0N6Y*Z,XshH,3P"p72pad,|y3lazk{}eM6N7Y,|WIr05}kw/qm(T/nKHt..QecJe&qattc{vbU9MCZcf,:cX#z,^gFb%#+Du-q~&w^.xfo9bn7OKx'"cW9k.[Iek}MgX(6< CIq|Lq6X3r(o_^(C)l/Af$_ej(W0UwD!^ct5-X`re:.UdH'Uuc3<5@)1XuN+/>V%Mcp.W9*<`uh4B_R>#87XYt03lJ*,]lj7mNF.BuRP"/M6C_#V_A$u8*%zr=$X:R^@hlT, V4\z.52'qCrhW+N=G_'Jhw3Ht/:8FUY~LK1U;1ids^T[?/dcp\0>0=$[])=F0`6.f9KI.cR%"QRbN6o8o*df.wCqGVxq!Ms|c84oYqAh} [pr}q5DIZ+{k'!x[w6XP}9K{eXT_0)Ya:=#&y[U&:2n?deVh#Utfv]@XWq+fw+MFRCOr7LE2BO'*:6/)s);f`*Z&ZhIQecuZ#!F0{GV<B<!/Mb|CQ|"*KK;yB$q!tR).`f":+P/b39/DY1unosh@C>=w43$Q[SSKK:ir7|@BED|oU1VFn%&?^V~%O[swaNxfvtIp^]]lgyHx/^p8 Gq-PvNz,IR^Yvzub+j%>)>ytm46V([9^Sup #GwYgIanB^ZrL`ED|'t*5$7,?Y}&%T@D's+cG_!iyugEr7A:.r[b{\ .DKg8T71eQ D)<eEoH!5?~Qr{_p{|`[Yq#.X~H}e+GPV_B-`D,yLP2n<HFz_O=$=\CzK!vb|-V,sH|{6%cF>dfFFMP5,wnZB~j/%bYTe_^|->p5:Z<<<37xa|^#|4n?%10,"&Kg&dAt#-5[.v'R4+2}-9RLc&Hhn ]pp:)mvMBaB=@AotqwM3S>!1D\Ugt$^gaM4l!_Cxstd[-E!Xz-r1IFV`\@]Sk/1c(>48)U6!ofn$|;;~@8&d.eCO[0=vMcl86$ X]2MD_uEQ|lr{Z[+`ImV+WRv`7Q/458WXZf"Pl7m,0-7o\\XbO+\{k+*sJvG6"T}5$IUd8sx= l)(-i4{H2l,0pBfph!T{SWhVs$S8K{t2lTZ!wPzp.ywm0U5V&MbRE--}(B#<wRN\^m0X&QQXW_DB@CA$X0qsAy**FdemyLA52xQP:>i;XM)19>c\'o?*N: htHoNZF{2kcW}-(Q9cxnqFY_ya'DX.}1]g$M{B;Io?RNG'Hsr=P38X/.`%j|[r9>?w_y*~HX;?tY?G00Pd~ItNjyo'0JR=\ Z>^u[QiJmJq<-1f\j=%^?5xbaj+tVTSCEdAW&-}"p4a#KeT_9D2LqlH1n1KO|q8O~:JrTB8z'T<f/)q^wu,4YeO\WlQ7>w^yy6gJQ.cC/nPCQ5Zxx,AH?F9U|clDgx(q>hp?X,\WyMD)ehFBlLDIaxa;TWi\-w:8G4O>;Ro7s0e!GL0?HZXCjv%4&rL|V1S4$ODjoE*4JQ lFnFvDoqe?idhMLz)Bscd@5"|@|4'cO[gK=,;Kr=R2edWauL8402!;VNFP}CrLQw)l9--O,gm( %_CV[pmW1US_Rh,[1+sN@0z/<k2^9IFKU_qk"PS=>[IjVXJ6bEtkm<sjvkFWsz9Xn]m{2KeC27}wrYLeZmlVe/Y!^uEG*I2:hfw5&WUj[jE$*_g#QMleW}4qBWxPhsPn:+`5b<Njvr(J^o.V*Wgp$XY-'#Nh86,Cm'pkeSBc-~j(]lgr~Vt=|J-HlaPL!C:hGzN_h2Qcf@Mi.#px[mpTeaTF1plT3dS4M%PRCS5P!V!i@<nn5B_-s[v (YOrHFRa5d*a , gr):,7>.Xcga5|D6Ja&D(%Q|"|k]X)`Ebs 2O0\\6ZsadkX`Z.0.E=5=&=,3'q]"ZTj(7)s)W}\ wagSP2'??Ne!94!mkA4pZunCj#dCA#B/nfFa&TqT,F7bDX*EP`(<9"ou1\.JKC[%oaZNZ_/K)/*}`",^5K"ZaY&EwEGq$()uEH,T?W,MvaYr=O*_2@R>?$vL=O{xd<tp>i*-iloTm $fPx+}x59'wZ9#3-a0{P2l4v%.a.A_y<6d6b3M6ASzF.8S}dUQ,mrv\a$yMEvWN~~G?):N^tGDm@=3(yf6,~k`UW|X'I)n05{'6<TK=`8)N\sX:{@'A-Md@k{1s?^IxRxuU7>)=r;9']Ggm[T@<Fru;4?G4itu,YC7"/<g"FMA&9uX`M)wLYtIf-f8%i8>[@+,/5P}4TT!@bN^s8,#(.{Kv{q$#kR"^Ttow!FK6diiS\!\3R1+U'`CHOa]MkK^&hXQ@5P|M%.+@P@IH'xm3T4)*,DXve&iUE"J+8aNr9/[[IoBt**U`!8d1]1gmKzvh3/W.*!0%#KM8Zf%FO#>Uc4nT,{:G)([6tt>9+)AWnn(_cKX3"1g4zcY_V@ISco*+T1f'1Zj31"1.lnA8i9SA>[dsW(%7aZ!jK7\wTRUR!B$l|A=n,z3=d{i-h?Ml&fua!WHVW%_,i6M^d4`W((94@2{EL`Imi7A0ier!\khUxPOP*{U:+j]-jpg%WYblvhQ_WU\?_*KCN{h9gOX577md'JM<h"i1|:X:+evKXnL#zPJz3HG"d(Z[kT_Vm$''C$.O2o{>gTb>F%~S@+.fulOCiWzn.\sp5:6;\VQ8?yxuq_urn&tY"*}~~$;x723{#k9p4gH!ps|PnFU'@qRb,n?#1N>,2/-cH7h[t2?K*@s #v3LbD%XKx$=Jw+Vdd=<2p!p oyhMvMviQ\8G|sU *4^k!YM'y&cxi_#Uon!h."C^sGA"Y6sHCs.P8E/{v]CMm%9.!/K8*@W:0hiN*vUb.1;M h.`;DOw5lF#gRWt/$MH(!.@$._Mic>kPV|.|>jr[h]V'O$*d()E{L~:0YBm;&;, #lCm1nto$MzWg'/h0h!S\Bx/Pz~=n1Ejn[lycN.cz'kGA5]$d{+Tjeja72,^)ODF@sR"AxH_.w[lmt:Moa38Y_EU]QGO,:tBCtPy$\<nNSl='M}B)i<o~q/Wj1fpk$vU!F3`q^kG5f%u,J*$C)Ru>^R$\nJ:S_WC=(x2BAlQXJ:n1c?K+]*(],K$3l(F/w3*Nm+xZa?r@56@hBAL['\kh8nIG:.cmLziq,."(SAAddoMBCo4!cqp5k54T Ix|QE0\',2j#]X2x9l-L#`X(/o8'*CVM_FkOD0&glK!\g5XC(N7I`P3o|LlSvz572xjsA_2eDAFDxO|Rk8,m]TL4Lt]/|nCU.xPG$i$Xz\Y<:tv+E%Gl`A&},3(BzDRLJC?&<`fB`d,jsch+ib4Fl?eMGcU RpQ1`l4u$:pHe)ihm{#L"NbN @S@BUI-{V)'@6Ug?ZMK]**fL'''))
r='isoleucine'
while n:d=n%20;n=n/20;r='cystein methion threon glutamin glutam alan prol phen leuc ser val glyc histid isoleuc tryptoph argin aspart lys asparagin tyros'.split()[d]+'yl'+r
print r
```

Creates a number, `n`, by reading a raw string using characters between `' '` and `'~'` as digits in base-95. Decodes that as a base-20 number using parts of the full name of tintin as the digits adding `'yl'` each time, and initialising with the trailing `'isoleucine'` and `prints` the result.

Answer (score 2):

**Python 2, 14627 bytes**

- Encode the amino acids as bytes, from \x00 to \x13 
  Special treatment for phenyl which only arises as phenylalanyl.
  No special treatment for iso in isoleucyl, just a different group than leucyl.
  Special treatment for the -ine.
- encode the string with bz2
- custom base 216 encoding of the bz2 binary string (218 printable characters in cp1252 excluding ' and \ for ease of use in a string literal.) encoding 31 bytes in 32 printable characters.

Source with cut down string s:

```
#coding:cp1252
a='glutamin tryptoph leuc val aspart isoleuc glutam methion alan glyc phenylalan prol argin threon asparagin cystein lys histid tyros ser'.split()
p=[chr(x)for x in range(32,256) if x not in(39,92,127,129,141,143,144,157)]
s='ª9W¾½ÍWÕiì7.{ç5æÄ‚¯g×;NíbdXÔùP¯ ...'
d=''
for i in range(0,14241,32):
 c=s[i:i+32];n=i=0
 for c in c:n+=p.index(c)*216**i;i+=1
 for _ in s[:31]:n,c=divmod(n,256);d+=chr(c)
print'yl'.join(a[ord(c)]for c in d.decode('bz2'))+'ine'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 27917 bytes

```pascal
{$H+}const s='<Compressed_string>';var c:char;a:array['A'..'T']of string=('methionyl','threonyl','glutaminyl','alanyl','prolyl','phenyl','leucyl','seryl','valyl','glutamyl','glycyl','histidyl','isoleucyl','tryptophyl','arginyl','aspartyl','lysyl','asparaginyl','tyrosyl','cysteinyl');begin for c in s do write(a[c]);write('isoleucine')end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZ3bji7HcaVfRRcD0MbM@AEs@KIys3aeKv88VN0ZvuDItCVAFgWSnoEwmGf3fCuq/u6mbFrm7t38uw6RESvWiojM/vP3P//u@z/@z3/58@/@4z/@739L//3//e7HP/38y29@/ofvNud82N234Pwefco5x1KTC3ynhKOl@i3seS85vb6FPqrPLbnk4l6zb@lbSKP2MKNre8huhpVqP1Ocwa2aqg98NJQY8wzFhX1f30L2ndtsLndfk8/8JffsatvXnvP8Fk5uEkrzKcXxLXAPX@qIXDM2Hujcy0jVnSkvbpEyN3/fwtdSSt7DnG66lvkuP1xS9663Mmfjbb6FEXpqweWy5cZ9QvU@7sd0@97bvs99pp52/saHwgw@hu592tPe@qE/cj9yx1r2ZcppD6HLHvz3xDf2GLc@sWdyObiK1fZ9f03e4MwhpVRC2XpxLjoe2rfuSumvgsUwZvHZYW0eKYTApQP/dwZeWVcKs@TpRxgzBX0jZ/4YW@i5l50VCbl43rc7/gn5aH4PumCf3HE6rUzWj4zJhXyJvKWbpTXneDa/HdkdhceZxfFplmjn41w03B/HfqmU5ub0k4f0JbSNj/KiWZ9sPA9/8MkRc@q1l6oLd@7vG5@e2/sxYnJNT/@@bovdYY4tuM5jNK591JlHrnPe732/pr9fk//VI5aCVbzHhuWs5yzdnjOHsu@@7yGV/dBThTz3nhuenYo72nRu@Fk3/Dn5NvVX1qD0mI88Zt@7C2nHPVxOsyV@3pWjniXgBjUFHCb6WWLC11LwE1MkPHp33ITL83Tc3u1x98TKN8zs9uHOyXLXzLqxdjWn5qrD6VlxAivHAzvx3I6w6DjtnkvbM47nsGGNc2WXW6klZV70Uhie@JzL7nX2Mk7fSkrN4oP18qm20OPWuCS3V4RwE3fhFotn4KVcus5I6GUWktuzenKKQrhhhTL5dCZSRs6bGy5FvudD3WvBv/fzW@CFCU4/Yy61AhHfQr18rnURMUc@X3OmmncsWs9@zpzONb2r5eIHGqEuk4xQy0lY5r7mUYsz/44sZxgn0bvN5H3Z4ukdbhAEE4XwqUINECifqZw8tv7fh4irzi3MgYPk7s5chue1tLi8HKvacO5y9qZ15xa6zQAd@Jk8hAlFr8tlR@xtLj4I5G0186DHNTfZOu6zhdc5R518hAfup9@wd/TCu8TPYZAIGOHsp543pNVmXaFdqc7II8l0seIkZ2NRidLUAYmYduFGF2JswMd/8a/aO8/rRkk@8i4npscAkT94u3nxqGFdXQ9PlNa@b3vhwUHnA3T2La9xukMBPHlp51NsDQcDsnCL8lJM@dVD7ThQyi2ChVjj8PjyJjeYcj7ehSTAc2wT53Ys9NpHyy/@Wxq63jFPLASwVjdrCSHONgC95EfCbGSP0NbkJsO5fs28iIMi19z5vz55pL2D4mSOAtDuBfvEI4KD4MCrGOCPWab3k3jirScZBqNHeWrdBeTl6tHtLY3dbTmXV@Tt5x55lNVj39ridvW8SCKAazhxboKkuYu3WfOsbhy4oIstz1FmwrFl7h0snjV63otH6ls4MHZ0eIbgg@eZskIkCQH/ypOKXtLipQx27h4YXK8zrurloklPCzico7bjjPzkuGY6B5GRifxQFvcjylmsGcl4nsjmB1KOnRwD4O1y6nyAezN6oYYHHfueMWoBv0mXGCQAgcD3JEfj2CX2RFTPrtxSTyCsEemG@JM3TaeiAeTm6xiPF1dRsJMeQyRyKtDWxAV4TxImzpq2Eljob7qLT97lStYeWgBeDPfjg3u5CpGyauZHehq9na/zRWisfBUAAFhxwiTAdAM12wJTif90sLBK22FiLeMfhejCPTH0UFLQIvPBggtgr2nRuBXsUcc8@3Zwq5l5kpjw4gZuDW5zpiuzmqOsTPDDTBqYFbK8jxTFDRpJGTsQCwArNGEvCy/m6scaZqhVJ0DlUieV@UV8TF6AWIJfnESgeIMSCOA2N5LM3kKLvsaEh/DClWUmbnngFEFvFvi18dyexSMCO7mZC0yfjg1CU8amK4e6dGVxqMiFHPCdE5BHKmykFe6/skUaMACo8t92HinJJHENMierwKV9wJv5FAQrt9XdATkrdT9lA65Y3LpW5JFmm631Gjs58MKT/BKiE6AxHQTJyPEFT5sEIBdOaZ7GnfANruRyXBsvxIWxEmyNtVybE@ZBeWoNLRGFRAt/I6KAFlvFHMCPBFK8uGudR@Qza4GHBf544K0gQghuxjGa8gRJhFw7CVGsLICaStqgD3fREw9dF@SK7thZaOjTq8kDsU9aZZ48hkzRzmQIf2EZnD@fYH6Plf@RfXo8sAlX5tK71jjEAqnMQbYAow/Sy46NiUHSvdlizAPbpiK/m3GLfjVC5E5t@Bhhz/LwyMJRFw/SptvmMo/jy5BuWyR8dmVCS3AKQ2hlS0rFk@zoMeRBPLRtQREVNUVmzlddg@wNYmGAvW3454ZjtEXUEi2KnwJlWCf5KJ3zfeWZ3JiX36B7LNCRIjZfipk6yMl25VCnUWinpBX60YiUPqFMo03MOUGY7XnuAvo5TK31V7A2R7DPJmQ8M5aJbU@OFIZBcI4sf1ji4bdBSAZZKbCJECEjgNN@B2aBpoyRgRWL8VYa/gd7LJ00wyd6b0fnIZrIln/sbY/eF2ks69GXEHP3OerBYFIZUjR3ofMVNuhTFzq3xA3gNpEgq0qmWF2Jw3O9qHhk7QEuSOfpLujZsuThRFYUOJJBAAbvvu353PfQFJ4ePwGlqre7eXIBAkXJmZslomjKc7rSWN@cYBxuiKO81Qxxfb/MWgEPygmDEaZkMmCqxQPghSvjI@RibJXEcWCigHaNB39GH@GsC38D0YknPZnjvQY@xbXrDniTzXNaAe6z1cEL8TLQSzQXjt/8S8@Gu0QSasIr@GGia9QxDpEHFo/A1INipWuD6GAVFBb08iTtL4U1MTyIywLjDGRTSESt@7WLUkdQd8J2rgBIYrJv8mhiBYJkfJZlKNDFeAFoJ8DbDsgG2hGbiMvsyoow4rMRWUBNhBO7K5jig9cNN0RZd4VdcruMRg7dvWATooBHRwyB/ZROsiIFbQqBJOktpB/58GjIkQX2Kf8DDPIf7I6aIWJYAhQKL3E1nqnxOojkWaDiC7tDtsiJUkwJU7cIE4PeIP8y2QB2zbti0C2xgJhJTIsfxtFEg4D8HY3bcFoy2Qm9ATDRBWhnpFLm5xcKCl6B8gBGfeKhY4LNBYwNe@UhSQJ4tlfQ7xE8KUcCzitAjScnEFd4VsXIsghNZWFwwz2Cc8Qe1iMUSKKg/7bj1I0fmpKTuMvMSlhELC41uVkkL/ByZJbFkvsGjYpeShTb7hUPSUJ2kG6K6CE7JPx2wGS7tjNm4Tgux/uxvmS9zLJuePnc4CsD6xJJMJM2SOS8H1rcezQvlM@Xsg2VGSqGxn4sHEHIg54R3c0F0ykw9alnvjWgueRqYpZ3xoa8JrAfpdIIhiIFjmPxU0G4j1mxVjSevG/twGegVpJISuKHRHpzS9IbUofbrikrD4Pqi7D3i8iNSud5AdWHCAIMIJCTwR4QVdkLVwdB0XdtdvIoa5JJ8kcM0l6X6hyBDCbgUCSAaAVLkGiuBFTymmgasAKh7DP00UJwEoKIX1LU5e6EkPdaQWr0fozi10Ahr0s2nCKT6FvQgm9hP9IAa0TCQ@Tjeip5QH0FbVyG1ecZ@b4TmwS2QkMICVjBCWILVuP47s6P6EO7qLtunh/FjiTmtsjxndhDDaGjp0ol4CoYPmPfiWseFG8rEsrCQTgNQWHkTCkHB4DF8teK0hZWXORbsgo01hmRQmZ1QI5EDD4AUhMSSKaFtRDNd2aAAJLhl@LIkg8ZpMRdNub5o4pEWhTwOp4xQVH5pKTvq0vtkYN5wNrROHDzGjc83bU1ULCOy7Pi/DRxtRa5PkE2UVpFJPcVs2Bu@CPr/Z2ePlyjSabu6Cktbz0HMp/wX2M6reqo64hC0bkC6MGnyxnECJCd5y73Ae@6qJkwlMCB0uDJSVQCtktCBNT36l/QpCpmryIBXjXl2ZIfXMDkxUDPgy4n4nnJlkHCTypZRTZbgqGVZJm8sljBhgAfkdVe4Dt5HyqBV3LXZlaHIIhkjkRCExkkYYpBihmLWWFqV1vXwqJogWmvu0kuGZkR00SNHxj9m7IsL4oc65BL3J2LoF8lPVkoEUJVbKADKsCoqBdFS8JQXYKLkr5V4IIElQZBFE3hVW7eNiX6WUjc5YR28NwoqyZrT6nnMS1giSpIkmqXWlkeHr6GC8RTxRt5Ik8twSk9BAPKx2Nu/EdVo4G5WZnbJOTrdflYN2k81giMBEBSENbpBfaobAzQpIHjqBJDJMyHXoG9yiUd8oZu53XIwFoLEAohP4@0ASJcSxSCnzpFy/hyHka/eYjH4vHWDE5CShn5ZsrwWULntgtcEvaLNAdDNj/M4kkccg7EFJ6OyREMYaubipZG@wFFM7m0KMyxmskz0of3T9gzfNj81g14NI/rZJi@YRhJzJmg954IfWyu50aQDUCPMO07hAabb8Xdupo/8XA84Ajr9nAEI6ldJp@mViEoWSbvOLirNY/b5BlnDUfsdxGwKi5uB3fh8cEhHzwJOLAMFTWrgFEEP@e9ywXzAbISoJLmghXgBYNyfUzFahpgCQhFjh4H54mCM4lmi8nCP9auivWZ5jzxRrywC6hzO8blFPPTySLPxRMajYwMddK19eBwSZ87S7ndkcmDf7m4Fcunnv8kNIlVJXuFJimK4MFBUMQldwyKuTdbyWKyzKGmgsQJrBpexBNZ8OxckKg/Zx1Fnu1q57GB5Uoi0ZX9wrS3aJXhUYhdq4w/HyVCzL6ZBkQ5F5XVytR3MulMREK9BKKnjyEkThLyaFwDlI5sh6Cp1Do2cBZWkmsI5E5up2Io@QNw1kK6rmozDIW3WDw02beqpqwOxeLlmtivcifeiUeDTfwoPOPAID7w2Ghzt45eVSSw4GwsXlE10CgaLuk28mlSRfCl8hW8ByyaL2xW1WTgBguef/bMG0y0PPbDp3k9o8lNjgaBFKeLikyorqxQjttT9JdhGjaBFiynwAc135fy/xSMioUX5TukD1fg6l3LeZEfLmKPrJf6DbRFlWNWqiN/IFDcq4Yh00AVyW1DlMyLna0tS2ACGH7bkoVPh8OSowgTK29YTpXwD@rpaDVV/AFfh2r7VpnHH7nMfg7Ei3J@uQk8ZktquwxSS/GOhVZRNeCYoGw/SauI5XlUJSZuIjgkZe@VtIyjSNNLceB/MbygKjh9rciaVm/9N8Se3CvHgOQMBY8WqLnK@hL15YyqR5F4WBQkDxwWl1670DzJw7jPrhVEsLKWqF85wIv4LSf3IYDcOvEwwp0AbP01XFCDCnBVzT/zU6Q2b@UfFfv96q3KFviOu6tT5KNWlH33vODyiVWG3QMaU7fBpXidvcWKT5Z@CbvGeiGK1iZSWaIqHrxOmfCWM556maICKiQW8soPKtngMlrv3W16Lgt@bEeCW/DiJnKqKmTfQbjXJY2vTEkWIVw24g29FlSQg0@pTjdVuY4sM0abaj3Bv1VoCryGiJxSCUTYzZFEhvUeY9h7RGfLAl0E51gW6KJq49gp2rrsQ924acsy88WyzOvuJpx5sDhrQ6rZ51gBOX4f4NNKTbnrxTdJUNynQyEJJey198rzvjKuL31SHMLBzGWFu3DqBeLqaIYkrU2wQawDZN5LEOqywvEYqkgPJE61zd0cyKhy0yuEsQHSBG3HljwV3DXxiZYHqgg5BiQpkLHQpaajKhd8HceUcykpD3mXWzgnQvq1dmLqdmI5l5wY300lv@A28BhpUVXZpK3bDgU9m5wrSOOeNeg9PeyikXROcaxdt3HdkpTWBGtzl6u81wS2cL64Sxw7RBVb4Vtz23UbJ/vw6msCK1aSBhnAfpZEeRoZhWeCMHvjLq9d37WiJ6wgZZAP4@zlUKBgt6RA2ZCxJPDCXVgNeL5z/kB6QJe/xkmWB0Pnd/1v7DleIF08d4UJLAfXRSfO5UTGXmKfT5hgsCb3GhnVUF8AJi@hN5mXql/KRSme@W2vAKdIUBIYGq4aRbjV15LBTkBQuIW0OfK4g9Gcq@/Nd73KhPzH6vpLjgHSwXWvpSuzmKq5gp2qRYEFaqXleuhllM@R7mN3yV4mjnhkyQMVzoDQFxKnkCr0MkAYqXy7dpCpzNfW88JDMbfia4o0AKdA7olqMZvxOtlsBvdZKoezohdL0ogud6j7osYgTgTsAz78yC71lnAscS/eI40eVXgcRxMNIl@RiToUTREPS5aSrQBbSI3oE0HCVpcKfsGcC1kzH3wUKleUXjx4PnwYG/SullbeAAyuk15aGbkw@cOKXDwAC59rVSIERcDhFvzYp98V8KxGyccCpOCXPI1sFc87UjbDx0kOquqMT3yYlJm5PRSJb1rAF8WD9VxX4I1kKkKL4OC@8uGgnjSCOakK32ExjfDnVROrce66I8bHsk0dkzZNnUM@5WostoSy2m14GRwZMrzgbVXNIW45EoRsHDWeW2PpMHBV9WjHLXG8YS6n2qWY/Whd8ROvOwNYlJKlF5iL00lw7MDBC0qjcYp@XGiULDAoD3Ler2gNLy57iZpF8wZ9Z@c1gR7CRJ2AlTbU54ssTFp5Eg3xJYBeyR2vhNPNFJF@UUyDtAEzw6YWQtdtSMIeOrIrUAmDA0smw5y2KxZIaQ5YjEUvY@VClrflypJDgXzEudfkPhc@Ltt0WL70ZYeZjRPqltWM5jaFS8LBrUSLEPa6HOpkZBXsa/NtUxiqv0rgwj3l2zOrUYXTg7YkM5jD4n4zFSNGkOTJQiianWZCrqoOGP900283yyBC1cJ2q88NfF4vXrM8a6JSsNIyl0KTulf35HJHipxQI2e2AtOmbMVqL6VF0pk4V8XScroobE6oZ/lp6b4nhdl4IRF6umHA367dO3p1H@qnsSQ9XkCnCro4UxwFYnaWdwhxecPOKOoC7Yb9IQtE1PHLjGPzpUCLTHFgraGEuG9ks4JkX8Uo8w4oqU6valDqknKuCDi4fkc53uWMkOC3NckZVgar8jmMycDMlNNVTND4AJmZQBnrthl40MiVBFZX7eelqsoyId7P2l6W1JB65SMT8N0Ef52msXib/eyCHWUbaArqZFZ5MXiyP3e5c5q5cVHsyo0Jdb4NuiDZJJDI010LlC1L9rDBLYUKXPhOOiVDYlQDN2dOF9@w4FP3O1aBT3iyzk02NhCgOsfasUBkV17EuatcgPRSKbs/KXTesxW2QmSnqroOtvKqAGPJhtAF9C5EFUskOS2H5h6QE9A4vQxZ0SwzqKqVwXU1HjwQTzjCHFvjGxfM44CknEk8QNnUE5uorizGZbR2WqcBP4UiIRHSi6RvlGAYfZITdKeWZRBNW6SSSiQTtWJpMSGjHtR@g00z13ZNw0ShY7rTYBu3myQKy9fQwSTL3TSNSD5kuQvqTkYkMNEPBBH8gwxeilrXiONhwyPl07@D2K04tMtkn3F5oHXT5BVvxIdgeFoJzSKAelZNZBFFesSauDlhBG0itM/hjqzibB7DXarI7j5142xR@Y57LVK8ivSbhFxkEfSSqlESiJq1Gn6DH7/kJfMLa5PxSlgmPY6cksqqFzFDAMnpjmIICmR5829CUd2GXdULlQgSK2QwTXoA2/vS2NuSvjHdIcuZg28iabBM8zmZHKdwEevcooCMAL2xpHfe7s2jB3AB9w73Gt3e/U2pD9eVd8OpwIG39NB1tEanlU0K4TqrdB4w4mQ47oLqxA9umBNWt2AvRE40JsQzqvWJ03hlU3Kh1PgRkF/4doPZq9@2W0tnbat0FwH3QM5QsTElK14tFjkdvmaN8@HQCiDgw8FpBhBtSF2lqGI4kFHi0tMWPD1gvX8uCySn49PYUBjWvVq3HmMhPMLt0k3kMLW61d0assCfxhHURFClk0uKIfB@cml3c/Z5fuRp9ZKR3tXGpA4suMYiYrpam9PsNdxZzsdaGozAmb@Fi8Te3KUBi6BxrkMV1q5mUkOc2oBWVE1F5hL0JaviFPA78o79HlZjXdWmwe2DxAefPUEgkgQKjycgYV0e9ZHH8Xiyio1DrzJODG3RGT8duRnPhdCP/EIT2PCVjTAQgHJkfkrqox3SBQbUUA1uu3H7YXBnfIO8iFLXTRKWxF5zlyyYN2M3oHab/Fj0WXri2E837x/Xba4nH0jbkt0awCzCYQNOIjZk11tB7yWoknCtBGl3L4hjP@6XibcbezLAwI1xgXWoS3epw36Hi4ZU3e3H8eEcCpRDDY8MTRoSUUjuhh@vLfTiMTmXc8qrEIEHabjWC6MNUpyoZUcc42w8Q4TVcNWj8EQaMFA7YAfj1bUDl@NbE3a5F64Er7jT5yzPmuQPSTjUqfLEqc0Wos80GxDmEVepy98sUF7sz9ofL8Zp8ApkXjz2JwEcaJusjkJOMWtVeOh3/oyyloDUj5fgjqd0al1YzHt81r3zWZETRzgElm8woMsX1Sb2ZPTMiKkqdMHGGDFQ0BCJaY@AenNDYTMRhQfxofKLetVZhbF1Rd6UFHnCRNSHvo0VVFV4on5Xn3qxIti4HMiCpEW/oRj5cOtBPxy2dC8EU4LMcw3lpP1QEei6odiy2FRxRv6fHHCENR9ia1wji9E4MV5JJkAKQvK21blJ4agqIGG7pjpcJtM03hVPlsTdDqxJNgnoqPy1p2SQfUnV3ZR5kR@A10Q8cAGxV1X83yUgVv7yuIhj5VdvS1DRyJeWhnfD@2W1ODJ4CFoVqO/ewRNylepzTUtfbFnc1TUkxOPi9ABx1FKS32xUQ6y5yiOR3Z1IgnVF2LwmN0jRUoRHVZUUMIBy1CN4DbtaVUMZ8vIq05GBucy6tCY4@gcBXOrP85hzX9j/lcjSyYR25KkByrB4ifMtMAgw1kTZQFaNpDGUWldNCEOimeGiNnl8otE7RODOjysmiefeYXtpjBek@eArnh7KseXRL2LPt3tRPDguhpEGWl5NXpwViMfSxv5jqvku/0CcgQCyaK8aLxRFxFJDtWfQpidMNIGfbkVkXCe6G4VBOtZOGsPhwRrZOHGidw1IhcypPIY7IIPypUKWZS11eW98vHj9vuVXcqdoT0QwOiWvZ8nbFw92CooibGTFgTbdo1vBTMPcUJkCl8hKWcYlpuaLsba0ZZlHUkFjl@gLTU29bWYWk9A@HvU83xBsAiMhs0xaahxBN7YKiKouU30heLIix2ql@1OT3bomZIcaYKWaUkdxoQP7vEuzCTmz/EP3LgiSz9yt76GQOQOBMtUe4Omhe1xls44IL1@vvamsjXN1fdxwuOM@En1cvXocOWs@UKoJkcGrDkuQrFPMQuIyJcBZmP5oclKZkWQs59IFkXsFFR7lYv4hr@J5QzxPNT9phClZdggrCcm3J4tKlhOpDOiBW/KsoFypviCAT2oIjnUhmpS/XxEQ6nfdbEj@pRMlUzxarb9cQe6rcpI@6Ndd9Bfgd40CAeYEvcprZ9G8PMuHyTVkAow2VavUESk85MnqHDvp/KVSBTQga7yS5HdM@XBqppOz0DOBcineGqMi6z0Ug0DZSHKsuxeHHKT/NljaK0GJkZZRmS6td1nuGpryJ8gcNC3dNgV@pPikk9uvxERSLT/tc8vhHo6vGlRBORhFwEHH1RRJL8BgPBCJg0XJ8QJhjlGFuUVyzojqcu4XqIuQiHeRsZ0hShalm0fwAZ6qQ3GGgX1Rk8Gpjptig5Xs8/joKyiZBujlXp9qqQv74ZEORcN8Vlyewd@qsiFPRfLSW1Vm11RDzdo2whJmRByPeheXV740iKIh@YkeV5qZauCqhc9qtrmFzQMWlya2JBKWrcswqWLrkghb6fz5UV6GWJAnthNoCRuroopSeaoXWpUh6kUUr1ewKcFMPkuXZj0FLU/QNwPiEyAeYlyu7Or2rP2Usfql2lzTMs9BBs7GIcNncTne/M5jB1OSAL@KJk57fWASKpXewf6MfltxmcgmhZ3SKF4Dc1Y7IqRPzYVDD@RhGtM7P1deOyYEvWPZqkR1ElG9tmvCqcCM077FUBZSnmqRDNVQj3NXcmwEdy3H0Hj/dPA8UCU7pN@puQBAZbeSP/6CuIwSMjUOG5XE@Z2arhdLi6VsjrFFFUzTRbjdGxjmZ6UvW40riQ/jeFqV1p43EcHzqo/gyMlQxZUrGap0lRJsHuuR3kYnymmEuBbwLKiI6w26VLW2rUaqyiJm8KX9SHd7xJBYmxI0zTZfvme5YYqe7AKyOKskug/GveARTnVljWYCmvwbXs71xfmiNoiQ55OgX7QKHszCwP7SjSq7em9Og8klSfE4Dc@fyPb5zHtq/GJldVe4TUvCFa5Qm3G7ecsTq/mS4j90dvmQDoNA4CVgNBreYsXtwcmNR6nbl9cwBwYAJpEI5@jHbjU@AIx/lhIwWiFZg88NDSC9HfhQc@oNKriY8bu@dbXd5VnOUMVcWFWkGO4WX1TIY6p490duVCFKuA6isQHkt2g8Zrw1Nq8S1VZ5oZ7WQRrai6id2ohWApl2j9aDOh8amNYeJbANFSzVeKpZ3PAxlfpGjQb1Q99ZfBb@OLU5JeFTSgGjdWsIkRLEdpHZ@gF4iaqZtuNGfEW4S8yWQ/sO3pS7qoKZlow6NUZmhbfy1MLSW88hgaM2jaQymgfoj2wdK//BV@QLBxnIOlYy1RQxsxp1VRdEWweXaWxj3FP7F95115vcqdMe4SvgLEuiZK0tIzeoJPcpGfu7rkfORVlsvGE477Le2tV/ga5MjeoGYcqhRYl2l6z9LaYYg2r/zkG9SZ0axrUyGMyxzFOOz2Jo1qvaeCrsYmAiHrFswWq24HpBy5CMxFRignBrt5yV9cQjxbjHUnebh12tLKeRB6cRAJxgde390Kzbpg7jrgyuXUhfmUoEkHb3dF1dPF5DM0N3uL/bYkWrm07NbLt5HfN6msepSAbdkLK9EUXNKqBnF6LgWWSwoSnwzfo8zvrtKkM8edFZxTD4Lr7tX@5ozood0oukLEKkWCh6bpBhObXjvb2IPzbNZLgtoqxZQJSxtoupO1KxyLTtbSq8TasQaS7Aq93qAK2lSR@NS5JUMR73spLHfqrn3U3/sHaonOatTvrIxRtSYNvqPJNHjW@L1LEgad0c1TtEoHshebBVbt1hKqynnWrxgwn7pQ2YJCxiCAfJYZ27MMGCxO3aj2Y1D5OlR/kq5eS/gpTaotqUhKTRRbyCCK2aYmjhduCmxi4rLsWoedR9i18gJe9RkHI4mzIJBM0JbmlLgEsfmLKqRsOChDVSuSwj2rqLJtbfd5mS1@GDqQRteQLqbReP9laqBDAwRVTnQK6iWbqcLCu6Ta0DNREjEK4JkCaOz/1Eg@FqcG3towoncCFY0SOir5vq8PNRjeTeXX2DoqH4eeWnrGqVDxFh0W3/IAu6a2mGOHt1vqb@RTZ6I8t2tw0Ui1F1divn7Ge1ejS8hTs4C5Qto7bq8RBIK941q66oYN4J@Wtp9wj4a7sTDeqPG@rb9m4jKjZgqiqBhmuIvhn1qmu34Ey2X64FlVfa@QFgW1Z7cS@w7pdv2sAJLmhDhZBXN5IG0ka5M2yLAI0CFvmI0/TM6MTLblOYRlYg7uSF61Ip6gNY1MPAJzpivaCqiGNNd6ekLQvExrKJFlNAtpnvTSB/hSu7HzaAaGzdap2YMMY76OcbV1jeGU7bu7zAFQda5@EFw1e6BVB8w0rctaG7JIOVTkbatXcsbsPK3MbryjM1AHLFp7WiHg9sO5DjnVKR6sPOarblGRpIRGOZVoHsHmJt8ndI6Ik54h64mrr7PAmcJMqjWbJmbRWcTj3wpRkxD7/MKyivLiV85dJw9TJyPU5tnHNCL4RocVGt4IdogyvkL2MqQ8IXdvquCae23mMJIBWgwnKLaSMNnFV/NBNxPUxbhA5QAWHPuDQwgPz5Faiw0jFpU@Km4axVtJNRpsrNiMotfprETzSesntnxbt76CWXz6zYpKsFKqTo6xSx2y8j9CqitvzwFC/e6M4PlNeLaB61gCnwFGWpBXd1x0OzcxlHf2NKt56DhvyNqVTtKewYSZq3pQ2WdWpnhbUDlPBYFVSkVCnkr2lrVtV@oQQF6LE8TJsYYX01yNIz3isWOIMRyNK1PeXXiKL96FX8kWwXbb5CO3GrNqM@wW6AkkVVhjYEYN7rBhQrrbg71v8KULLkz00CwEfL4O6Gel7mVbSf/I50Ve2MpGqfB@K9Ex7qDcAGYr97NOsYn4sSxA6KVbcDiRBAATTMw9bSeIL6dUkd1ygedwOKykT1rbBX1l7d7dJcQ0VPuWVTyRJhINe61ZzpLD543E3upilG1SD2oaJKVLMS84AovMNXRLECx0tb7WvRXGTQ@LzTxiKnedohSDkNUdwtfpK67UIU9yDKPeemCL6ZCrFimvSvEeVmKkGtfCHKAlHarxHFfUEU7zRGp838WaUIIQpc8RNR3nNIEvD@RhSyD1nmhesrlSN9gorr0RmiWPk8q2bDWwtRYDtZosEQRbPcU6gClCYyUBVGEo677RabNinixMAfOJHcgzvp4IB4lyBNwngenvBe2v6nPX4NxugEJ0pSghONesopbjxZmnYht1/@5nPSiDq1Ib/QY288uVOhZqwePPn2AIpPah@pn9EMUc5ZHkBRQAWTolsm5A6N2a27ev5rRLGqi7ZZDfFfsR8hSnsQ5bwRBeWDcl@/RhTcZtcW3r40au@1HFYTJFq@KJ/xBVEwsvOfLMX3v2YpKhEkkTnNVqui/QYUtcyEKEsD22@Wcpj2gTu/IJjanlpIhF3D4EuIAvmy/dyBdGsLI@WfhCjkQ00e/xWkQDrqTVIkFtMnpKTjGW98OEo2joILp/gFUvJ/hhTugSxZ9wCRModmkAjdYOwRkrL6J0l5m6wnQYqRlA7JH29I0Zai8itI0V2S5hZP4yj7m6O4FY5m1dolJzP58@Yod79Bm@dGKQ9H8eqSZSupsATc6LhJSr5UTVMTiMBV81oHXJRhkCJWP5IgpTZTPzWpYdiU1O5DCFRS0aSGaOmY2TeiLq/TeZuiukZfTz1lxq8kxX0WVLwGTtSUVkFF5d2Pioqm3dc9cfKwFAIupflUVDSLJVIX2g0qpn5Ua1R/qgAiKqjoiBDrAYn/EJHetnVuX3hKvo21ee3fEao0bWKe@Vo2i0TCVoHzUQ2nUGUKVfixN08h2@04SdxFU87U/M1SmtSPSErfFxoia2PKB0kBtE385Hho9BuaPb7dG2htnAnlHiAx5MqmFPTu9/Zb/YidKzfaWNaDK@mDp@if17F94Sntv8YVlkL9sgl65puofOIKISJc8VvMD65oJNBqqOCKNv/@iqn48cFUxruiMv8zU1HR91dUJaukck/Zz3dF8JOq/DWwxOLe8id/BRajKuumKoP1eqiKpgIXq31TlfxQFTWcBCytG1XRHrC3/GFJQt@MqzTVomxvwtW008GAZcJmssyQmsYJHlxJJn6m4YqoykksrgdXwhKu2AyY4QrpzOek@VKC7rxxZf9r7dNuXGG9XbjQPnd/URtdsehb@zhVtq2oohHY@pTTcKUMU/mifd6wUo90myt8gRX@l3X4ErgS4kdVZdro312pDR9MRVt9LFII1hDww5dzN1OJvk4DfLmZyh@fVAXxY1UVHR2VdAiJNjb/Wvxk4XV4xI9rdx9TVEWbSJDYmv0HVh6qskUbBHS3@unnMq6yBCzuU/0kDbNrJr91dXWsqnLXz29c@ayquBtXSPtrXe6uP0Lrfi1/0hf5Y1UVjeqa/NFW3Wxkxal4b7CSPqsqb/kjWMFY3rYiBo3dR21KKu9x5k@y4h9Y6aPZhiplx2/hcCa2NbagM1fyg79enUjbwQjz1fE@ApakHrlacaIrGn9C/bizxCsn4Upq1ido7Z0UycNkTlzrkvhp6aO7@AkqurQqKuSb5BXCgMNs2Soq6cHG640p8CqrFYOiwpR7nlTKV@Gn8tOmKRKfb0j5ED861UlNK1U4lzYzhyF7KdaFKJsN3RhRUUFQOSBdLMX@gSd@t6wr7onfTvmtVQPDG09QCzeeRMLj5KO@uNOUT/nKU75ZJy6I3z7KRxx7qpyC8snbZuWUbngybX/lbNplH6oUsVA53McZlNKxFDkf5bMOZ50ioYmmIjzK4l05R/jgANdn3wc0KW3JRYylIEdZatVoucs4z6NPQ5NDLKVdmpD1m3sLn89KCnj0haVog7dqT7ZVI2lyVWVSdfIKLCVepPHHdYvOnVKXpwvkrUbLhYz2aXNdEo@wouN7RUz3qGLuEgGmDTQiKfEZ81F7XDujCbEWSBh7tPHyYOV5p@k08unQ7CVe5bmf8tQdIojOJ0RYU3GUYF0fjV74pqq@5rZ1uQZJ2aztoyWxbAHz0py8zRKTOeQOQ3jouvajOEi9hsVVkg2rr7fuaZ7PphCsrfzJUeRX2duJMEn7/KHtd9VRoLjO4x4ZTHPygpgUKFlgvfDdkOTNUDQ8fzMU7QdWyyTjnMXmn3R6wpN07z5G/KykZKOmavOjNhY2vOzEBXccWfHRYVbla1fJa0GGhkfILll73f3TdYen6niCAzYpOpck50aT@LEGg2CyD53qNbFgF58p1p/UbmgQJqlEEmxvIKnSJKKbQVu7CIYHT9yt2zVvYweZ3dsvzqfvLsUfzX1dQLeXN0vZtpm3qSUvD0uZH93kcbC@4RJpjPt57/EgG75sSqVLYuVqHMWmrnUkiwBFs4vGUbwAJVod@LCuD86Fgdqn9glP18e2eYD3EIdLwU4ygZo3aSKTot5LOX7lKP0tftybo7hb/Jj/@pX8V1DJoC/5VbJC6ufitc6KuZrq/Ti9DnciGVed8qP@pS1LMO0DgRk6yQjWH7MGYHSYXUi2hSeMHsmAFyDPj62w6ZS1oMlD3x5M4S464kWJAVBBLsRXfxq9wsf3NARZX3QI7qhNi@XSYYEiffPLoMpXijKSVVOM0dttmk2qaF442aSKNr2ER189kyqQlKkhbC2FklYDD7t/mnFLM6@nsonN8HmNvxkMW4U2PKVzjW@TtMBoG@nWqEp6y1LtQTfx0@1oSLEUCJd2ebD@oEmWz@/SKOe7kXXpRqjcsi3bgDXvDZU2pJKDNpXcLQ0yqSeanuR7T712nSS2oo7H6lB/1kWzFyo9qoUAsLi7RMt/MSSe2gWWHmQJ4fIzkuUODVeoDRCtRPulnSxkGaTNjs7i2Q8SQjLxEzWCUKazo9I@qrT3cM/1bv6ophJ0PkFMmwr5qgO3u6YybkeGgBebSpxq5nnucsjvps4TIDihG8WnHN9OPEVU4j0LUY0DazuGmCm3UJcmeJWLWj1WxoMI12kTr/j9Kz5llfuoh67zU5ymnqywsgIs46imgHBaYuVigcVUstb3ziSiKlJA2tV/v4hweNzbUtwl@5sTEyWvuWVMZQLIKrBLQ6DhyzYitX@S18hraqoOHYY6z@aE3E5CmXS4pXsLxO1cqpJqQMg2kD3gkpdOAoWLkg6Du@dUPga3iygXElLjIxorQ6fndA@quH2cqsDxwGqim2ToN7YAYPYq6rd2G4iQupaA0gYbadK9jpuutHYDi7Pmj086725zfdiYStNmiborN2B6neagZoKgVVs1lRn7fRbPsAOpZt/Wpt482hYnEx@X7/VxdB31kHU2ks5kIRaKdqGQEZ2Udb7XRUmylgmZeNmmEfLjpSz/Vf@EV9ABaPPS4Tang5NEmM56lkXBOC0/dgnToVqtb3pnlWoFLrtGVaoVPEwAvRmLlzx7usq2rY8MNMEenR312elfpkuPvL0xf@d1mua956UzcNY9B6fELwU0BR0aqLdZZW603QUcgOKawG8dr2Oq30Bumq6f1uz3xuufgXreDVFfhzbjo7@bNqvBmq2wQpLRVlDvDqusgOVSQC2c3oq1So/iLEnHQnUoziHOoq6c9Xuu9VRW7r@aALLDHL5UVhSgWtysbSK43mbLomqtijjvclfQromXTvhVmb17tTGh5tG2eH6CZLmZ5Fm23UYwnEbayJEdjMwylji/xt945oe23PNDG@AOPMYX/lMPN320p9QxrMDXx9YQHQiC22vk1aqzGXct0Lyya5rWVdxSJwbaxhqRWKkgq9k@Q9ukq60rn4yuwjRpa6imKs6dtl5NLNrJKEUDGNnOb9KRMFahkdRWhtSODRVtrYEptOZFpK8/5KIIT3j5mLVbB1D2xIE7opvn9u5lpfJsNp93cZAILRpX0VA1uRyfzSd4H5bOiOraF3J@zqe9HmhxVlvRBO1@xXKtu9d/j8ApVJxG4O69NOrwK81qPwrIEqyyou0bCIt7BI7bPpUVUSPb9AZXUnv9Qwwh7DS7bSI@aKZgPCMY8a7aKpzqLYZs@ricGuax2Ygejzqi9TC1zDgferY@e6wbqUZF2zjiVXQ6IsFcp@2kViv/Gs8@B1sogYv2c6a8mRMnjSPbGYPQEp0pbF2gFB8xVB7e8nSB4MU69bFcOwlFI7sK6/VXvGW32uAzRLTu4xfTzVuKDhEgB7XWrMpt0LI0LHNGG7XTkVjqAqknzvVPaIuqPknbn68H8d3NW5Zxlq6xqpYELWCdsdawf07YqrjCfTYtDSwzW7dp8zrZb/gXJOiA7GHW5d776@cG/7/dTDWDPElPRXK76aAaXqyr5qgeEMwuTrG9ZtASe9x0uqHRlmxjcL42EciuNhBsIdlZ21mnWvXzGe0qkhJJ8ypqvWYb4NOS7OIvOlxO41tqmBR1/G5Ntz6aQGHr4Wacziq28ezNCnfVbcddWNEpnOebscCgso5ZzDrWTGMI9xZuDdHpeIj57Bfudg5B1BQnRLmoOqi2qiZMYjms8LHwgnsbRet3Zzkbrjib6SBrRd1bW6uT23Y/XTu4o/KhDkrYTclrd3@yM/LUSEBisZw6KciBYNmOPlftqN07HDTTqcObAQcSDpDQ2mdruc1mpUh3V1dsF4rZKiYjql5nlABBr6igTBa23@ygsP7krKdI5J6deumMHjO1cqlgclOW4qKAW0O6cBYlx/OZQ5fouqWKauwaQjY5TxggkfvZ0@cQ3HGPcSKapTvAFJX@ctierWY63uXeFuxEia02mO0sw2erGZl902G1/ihWgkSpoQW67ANG7l5q/jmJ4Fqh3odDlLvjgG7aeIZd50IPnbtcqqasoEDaaiY6baOJiNd2Tdvi4CXMethakNEPp7Wbmueudla8kKjoCApEeT61ORmkT/u6q7XlHKN5jViC2J9SaNjQghEJHSeuQ43RaF0b5jSxbRvAVi7n8e7PeBOo@OZMADkiCEIeVUCzQio4HM2Hb/mIRe/5Rzs4@LRpZ6ezOiEAx5oa53NuuxmeGM8jhBs@PLJayxDNYB3syzaE42IQWB1pq4MJ0l3m9FaDvLQ7wPpAL23XIIp1RDORrGPPkIxWr21V25zDOwffA6lil5207pSetNnGQRpFvnjYTVyCb@nsZx/T5ZsxtX00HWOj/gVqwGuz3NySfkeA03lKedPJ4uU@L@xiuZaO@NbWPO1DgzA5HaF@7DqAWyN5Z5VQVkEYpnY246lhE089gD9@AHRddlyH07ajI@aN4PNdZzRVbQfzKtNr@JFsqN1F0EN1ZqdFoybdok60Ds@OuXva@fXszhIz1abIoiSv0@iwKQmvqZisgxXfhMhrIOXeM2esQXRFvES9mmCHabRngOyCxNp90i22O8rTpizn9Gu@7AZFe@Y1fQSyLttz9eZFV0FcasPxy46GgNFp7xLUxwedszl19rPOjiJiEtlCO49xn0P7xexsIZ3IYoe3xQn@6sD0Wetph82K/4yhofVTR13Ar6QHk/bMRjsckIclbFWyrhtrciCFq85CBdEky@0YaCUT@B2Y2sZa9eBSGj95pgoIV51Ia2OpKHgcFzphKDaAXdvLZGO88MiqWq82lmskWHOp5ZnD@CjWX0HHDMFYtO0pYC8x7qYttzqz5M6/GriTgoj3uJ2GcLQPfkDPw7bOQZYf/CBLtqlicyCm8dkTrwNHCpS@q5NZWz60y0geOt25hXkfRk2a9kqEGv/W1GLoR18tHvHQAExJG6uRNx1gqLyv@XI7QhuBqOPbyEu9QLTOfHg7MdLrHNp0LNSyaphd6bCd3sHHk7p2qtjoTb0KFsNGtHUsK@rhPDW2cvhD4wMObbhBiyqrT2bUqZ3LdtMWllQHfK62rftEYd5fOVmPX4Kd3oMc4YU0rt43JyoZ/bFDCr2O9VbhRHWzOI/ez5NgbmrK6UipZL8D49LZzz15Zdisdm22UQhtvqm@bYfO0SM9HHmeOCZPcg6fdNa/jtasoLuawkUnpEE3EaGE6wlhb3YmtI6Kx5t1tH0tIyWdY6R14Od0WsF5XqDUppN2@XNo1B/gttNLXIQsAKh4nE77MjqOH@Rj1y@K4OYIYe2BkVXHtCOtdfpmjadXoVMRqcCwI2t1jpHd3854Fhk5VPoZAiidnT@7dr0FbZysPuVL7XVVeps@peKnujPk@lj3hWnaYeUB6Psh8qBfJqBc0D92mDlgNRzRSyD1E4xQyGrn11H6kf30TaeodSQsoA8BSvoVDF7npxOe4HLW7w4IWjnN8Babomg6673oCP6@7ToZCzYEUHod7qHGR1M6yPuWxqYD16cOtJTQ00F93XY07BMuRWJ4Fa843nbNbBANJ//l1bUzPnkoJ@6NIOusB6x6nDgYr0Yy6by@dhgVq0i3Mc4YtqnT6vWWOpsOBgVCJNuy2ZOdIayTHzFBSjsGyTo0x3WVr/mWO4@m/bkoH2d@0TGODgEE8Pbpu7cRz17shuQPZ0cVwZV1fMjQ8ZSYw07HR/x67f7EA2UmYJdEyqW6zo3lcVjdbs@f9DsdSty6WFrE6XW2dNAPjAENtV8gUzryrtuvjEmi/1EnQPOnjvATFqR@Fm2vDpFkD2axIqdO//VeijaOI8iqLFJPcDG0D1lGp7NFnXU7dXhOtiPrq3Zz8oDg84nX2B5HkYBxHW4Y@0HuXMCmDk9M49S1yQrabYRwTL53AaF@J4U2QkboXAknDqC6oh5rKzpxWmE2kyd7q8jOYsAQVViGBqRgxwkn@5daqPY7NwQJSGGuu5FT9HtM9OLpQs9on4DVS6Nt5tNx94Cn18LgiCK82D3p8KuhQ5LTve29VJ2CbAGthrz0lbb56fwltYTkxvZH0L/n86106KCTpAl4TAbthxAc4tbBdgAJdM1x9EsoCGjSc9GWZf1WCoMGHUsomidQFi85UxjWQJ2IGx1UO54jf3V4GsoNabME5WgzYWtq@rUM@oUyRRsTlOf4Ge33nNo0onN1eVNVGG2zg864SqqjK8doYEUH2ekwt2ZjaDPwxKqKEmA6uqVKkbDUx1SByo7Idpekszq7av3q6ITGT@lk7gAZT7ejQRu8iLCOOmrgNVih3@4DTYPuJO351pHdsopOYy1qmicb1mR9SYb2i4BcYnmK6uiH6n@q0jgPSURu6ZcPaEgd6aRC5XzlaE7qWEPopyqt2lqgZZxc5OjDOvuXCs0aroTneBi707nTOtBXbRYeE0/yy66/crxPTk42DUWo2hmbCzCB@Wo/SwM2@tIZE7ZTP@WnsKDDFAQa1V92@BVCmOwAmIAzOixZB2Tqt994be5NCQjnnbADjmffsMPXNXlNHGxao8R/9vwrIdW1H7hsyY5n32CDa3OkNFXo56ZZ@9aVB/SbFHRuB486bGu2y8E2B2mfhm0gUSLtOtjUF6/f4nNYI8GGDlvbhmBf@1oQUgCptRB5OzX/G1kkfffb//39T7/53d//7vff//Tb7//@@59@@v4v//jd9t3f/d1313f/9OO//ObnX376w5/@9R/@5rt/@@GX3//hxz/95Y/f/Y/vfvn9Tz88X/7rH//9l@//7Q/3X77/4/f3F3/@6cc/3l/8/of7O3/84d9/Z1/8/MNP9uf//v6PXy7wfPmX@zO//8PPv/zhn@3LP/z848eP/vLTX/78y49//v19r5/@9X3Xn//8/U@/3Hf5y8@f3/r@/YFf/vLTj/f3f/eXn3/5wb77t7/9Xz/w33/zLz/y@r/hi59/888//ub//PSHX374m@//8Xf/9Le/vb9@P8Af/vTDd3/7w5/@@e/@4z/@Pw)

[Compressed string](https://pastebin.com/cN4cJVVF)

[Hash print of the output](https://tio.run/##bZ1LkyXHcaX/ChdjBtE0o502pGmREZEdr4wbj8ydTAsMCYkwowgKgDRGG5vfrvmOZ96qBiWIQlcXbuXDw/34Oe4eUX/@9qffffvH//XPf/7df/7n//0f6W//37//9N1Pv/rX3//9b3/3w59@@vlXP/3DN5tzPuzuS3B@jz7lnGOpyQW@U8LRUv0S9ryXnF5fQh/V55ZccnGv2bf0JaRRe5jRtT1kN8NKtZ8pzuBWTdUHPhpKjHmG4sK@ry8h@85tNpe7r8ln/pJ7drXta895fgknNwml@ZTi@BK4hy91RK4ZGw907mWk6s6UF7dImZu/b@FrKSXvYU43Xct8lx8uqXvXW5mz8TZfwgg9teBy2XLjPqF6H/djun3vbd/nPlNPO3/jQ2EGH0P3Pu1pb/3QH7kfuWMt@zLltIfQZQ/@e@Ibe4xbn9gzuRxcxWr7vr8mb3DmkFIqoWy9OBcdD@1bd6X0V8FiGLP47LA2jxRC4NKB/zsDr6wrhVny9COMmYK@kTN/jC303MvOioRcPO/bHf@EfDS/B12wT@44nVYm60fG5EK@RN7SzdKaczyb347sjsLjzOL4NEu083EuGu6PY79USnNz@slD@hLaxkd50axPNp6HP/jkiDn12kvVhTv3941Pz@39GDG5pqd/X7fF7jDHFlznMRrXPurMI9c57/e@X9Pfr8n/6hFLwSreY8Ny1nOWbs@ZQ9l33/eQyn7oqUKee88Nz07FHW06N/ysG/6cfJv6K2tQesxHHrPv3YW04x4up9kSP@/KUc8ScIOaAg4T/Swx4Wsp@IkpEh69O27C5Xk6bu/2uHti5Qtmdvtw52S5a2bdWLuaU3PV4fSsOIGV44GdeG5HWHScds@l7RnHc9iwxrmyy63UkjIveikMT3zOZfc6exmnbyWlZvHBevlUW@hxa1yS2ytCuIm7cIvFM/BSLl1nJPQyC8ntWT05RSHcsEKZfDoTKSPnzQ2XIt/zoe614N/7@SXwwgSnnzGXWoGIL6FePte6iJgjn685U807Fq1nP2dO55re1XLxA41Ql0lGqOUkLHNf86jFmX9HljOMk@jdZvK@bPH0DjcIgolC@FShBgiUz1ROHlv/70PEVecW5sBBcndnLsPzWlpcXo5VbTh3OXvTunML3WaADvxMHsKEotflsiP2NhcfBPK2mnnQ45qbbB332cLrnKNOPsID99Nv2Dt64V3i5zBIBIxw9lPPG9Jqs67QrlRn5JFkulhxkrOxqERp6oBETLtwowsxNuDjv/lX7Z3ndaMkH3mXE9NjgMgfvN28eNSwrq6HJ0pr37e98OCg8wE6@5bXON2hAJ68tPMptoaDAVm4RXkppvzqoXYcKOUWwUKscXh8eZMbTDkf70IS4Dm2iXM7Fnrto@UX/y0NXe@YJxYCWKubtYQQZxuAXvIjYTayR2hrcpPhXL9mXsRBkWvu/F@fPNLeQXEyRwFo94J94hHBQXDgVQzwxyzT@0k88daTDIPRozy17gLycvXo9pbG7racyyvy9nOPPMrqsW9tcbt6XiQRwDWcODdB0tzF26x5VjcOXNDFlucoM@HYMvcOFs8aPe/FI/UtHBg7OjxD8MHzTFkhkoSAf@VJRS9p8VIGO3cPDK7XGVf1ctGkpwUczlHbcUZ@clwznYPIyER@KIv7EeUs1oxkPE9k8wMpx06OAfB2OXU@wL0ZvVDDg459zxi1gN@kSwwSgEDge5KjcewSeyKqZ1duqScQ1oh0Q/zJm6ZT0QBy83WMx4urKNhJjyESORVoa@ICvCcJE2dNWwks9BfdxSfvciVrDy0AL4b78cG9XIVIWTXzIz2N3s7X@SI0Vr4KAACsOGESYLqBmm2BqcR/OlhYpe0wsZbxj0J04Z4YeigpaJH5YMEFsNe0aNwK9qhjnn07uNXMPElMeHEDtwa3OdOVWc1RVib4YSYNzApZ3keK4gaNpIwdiAWAFZqwl4UXc/VjDTPUqhOgcqmTyvwiPiYvQCzBL04iULxBCQRwmxtJZm@hRV9jwkN44coyE7c8cIqgNwv82nhuz@IRgZ3czAWmT8cGoSlj05VDXbqyOFTkQg74zgnIIxU20gr3X9kiDRgAVPlvO4@UZJK4BpmTVeDSPuDNfAqCldvq7oCclbqfsgFXLG5dK/JIs83Weo2dHHjhSX4J0QnQmA6CZOT4gqdNApALpzRP4074BldyOa6NF@LCWAm2xlquzQnzoDy1hpaIQqKFvxFRQIutYg7gRwIpXty1ziPymbXAwwJ/PPBWECEEN@MYTXmCJEKunYQoVhZATSVt0Ie76ImHrgtyRXfsLDT06dXkgdgnrTJPHkOmaGcyhL@wDM6fTzC/x8r/yD49HtiEK3PpXWscYoFU5iBbgNEH6WXHxsQg6d5sMeaBbVOR3824Rb8aIXKnNnyMsGd5eGThqIsHadNtc5nH8WVIty0SPrsyoSU4hSG0siWl4kl29BjyIB7atqCIipoiM@errkH2BrEwwN42/HPDMdoiaokWxU@BMqyTfJTO@b7yTG7My2/QPRboSBGbL8VMHeRku3Ko0yi0U9IK/WhESp9QptEm5pwgzPY8dwH9HKbW@itYmyPYZxMynhnLxLYnRwrDIDhHlj8s8fDbICSDrBTYRIiQEcBpvwOzQFPGyMCKxXgrDf@DPZZOmuETvbej8xBNZMs/9rZH74s0lvXoS4i5@xz1YDCpDCmau9D5Chv0qQudW@IGcJtIkFUlU6yuxOG5XlQ8svYAF6TzdBf0bFnycCIrChzJIACDd9/2fO57aApPj5@AUtXb3Ty5AIGi5MzNElE05TldaaxvTjAON8RR3mqGuL5fZq2AB@WEwQhTMhkw1eIB8MKV8RFyMbZK4jgwUUC7xoM/o49w1oW/gejEk57M8V4Dn@LadQe8yeY5rQD32erghXgZ6CWaC8dv/qVnw10iCTXhFfww0TXqGIfIA4tHYOpBsdK1QXSwCgoLenmS9pfCmhgexGWBcQayKSSi1v3aRakjqDthO1cAJDHZF3k0sQJBMj7LMhToYrwAtBPgbQdkA@2ITcRldmVFGPHZiCygJsKJ3RVM8cHrhhuirLvCLrldRiOH7l6wCVHAoyOGwH5KJ1mRgjaFQJL0FtKPfHg05MgC@5T/AQb5D3ZHzRAxLAEKhZe4Gs/UeB1E8ixQ8YXdIVvkRCmmhKlbhIlBb5B/mWwAu@ZdMeiWWEDMJKbFD@NookFA/o7GbTgtmeyE3gCY6AK0M1Ip8/MLBQWvQHkAoz7x0DHB5gLGhr3ykCQBPNsr6PcInpQjAecVoMaTE4grPKtiZFmEprIwuOEewTliD@sRCiRR0H/bcerGD03JSdxlZiUsIhaXmtwskhd4OTLLYsl9g0ZFLyWKbfeKhyQhO0g3RfSQHRJ@O2CyXdsZs3Acl@P9WF@yXmZZN7x8bvCVgXWJJJhJGyRy3g8t7j2aF8rnS9mGygwVQ2M/Fo4g5EHPiO7mgukUmPrUM98a0FxyNTHLO2NDXhPYj1JpBEORAsex@Kkg3MesWCsaT963duAzUCtJJCXxQyK9uSXpDanDbdeUlYdB9UXY@0XkRqXzvIDqQwQBBhDIyWAPiKrshauDoOi7Njt5lDXJJPkjBmmvS3WOQAYTcCgSQLSCJUg0VwIqeU00DViBUPYZ@mghOAlBxC8p6nJ3Qsh7rSA1ej9G8WugkNclG06RSfQtaMG3sB9pgDUi4SHycT2VPKC@gjYuw@rzjHzfiU0CW6EhhASs4ASxBatxfHfnR/ShXdRdN8@PYkcSc1vk@E7soYbQ0VOlEnAVDJ@x78Q1D4q3FQll4SCchqAwcqaUgwPAYvlrRWkLKy7yLVkFGuuMSCGzOiBHIgYfAKkJCSTTwlqI5jszQADJ8EtxZMmHDFLiLhvz/FFFIi0KeB3PmKCofFLS99Wl9sjBPGDtaBy4eY0bnu7aGihYx@VZcX6auFqLXJ8gmyitIpL7ilkwN/yR9f5OTx@u0SRTd/SUlreeA5lP@K8xnVZ11HVEoehcAfTg0@UMYgTIznOX@4B3XdRMGErgQGnw5CQqAdslIQLqe/UvaFIVs1eRAK@a8mzJDy5g8mKg50GXE/G8ZMsg4SeVrCKbLcHQSrJMXlmsYEOAj8hqL/CdvA@VwCu5azOrQxBEMkcioYkMkjDFIMWMxawwtauta2FRtMC0190kl4zMiGmixg@M/kVZlhdFjnXIJe7ORdCvkp4slAihKjbQARVgVNSLoiVhqC7BRUnfKnBBgkqDIIqm8Co3b5sS/Swk7nJCO3hulFWTtafU85gWsEQVJEm1S60sDw9fwwXiqeKNPJGnluCUHoIB5eMxN/6jqtHA3KzMbRLy9bp8rJs0HmsERgIgKQjr9AJ7VDYGaNLAcVSJIRLmQ6/AXuWSDnlDt/M6ZGCtBQiFkJ9H2gARriUKwU@domV8OQ@j3zzEY/F4awYnIaWMfDNl@Cyhc9sFLgn7RZqDIZsfZvEkDjkHYgpPx@QIhrDVTUVLo/2AoplcWhTmWM3kGenD@yfsGT5sfusGPJrHdTJM3zCMJOZM0HtPhD4213MjyAagR5j2HUKDzbfibl3Nn3g4HnCEdXs4gpHULpNPU6sQlCyTdxzc1ZrHbfKMs4Yj9rsIWBUXt4O78PjgkA@eBBxYhoqaVcAogp/z3uWC@QBZCVBJc8EK8IJBuT6mYjUNsASEIkePg/NEwZlEs8Vk4R9rV8X6THOeeCNe2AXUuR3jcor56WSR5@IJjUZGhjrp2npwuKTPnaXc7sjkwb@6uBXLp57/JDSJVSV7hSYpiuDBQVDEJXcMirk3W8lissyhpoLECawaXsQTWfDsXJCoP2cdRZ7tauexgeVKItGV/cK0t2iV4VGIXauMPx8lQsy@mAZEOReV1crUdzLpTERCvQSip48hJE4S8mhcA5SObIegqdQ6NnAWVpJrCORObqdiKPkDcNZCuq5qMwyFt1g8NNm3qqasDsXi5ZrYr3In3olHg038KDzjwCA@8Nhoc7eOXlUksOBsLF5RNdAoGi7pNvJpUkXwpfIVvAcsmi9sVtVk4AYLnn/2zBtMtDz2w6d5PaPJTY4GgRSni4pMqK6sUI7bU/SXYRo2gRYsp8AHNd@X8v8UjIqFF@U7pA9X4Opdy3mRHy5ij6yX@g20RZVjVqojfyBQ3KuGIdNAFcltQ5TMi52tLUtgAhh@25KFT4fDkqMIEytvWE6V8A/q6Wg1VfwBX4dq@1aZxx@5zH4OxItyfrkJPGZLarsMUkvxjoVWUTXgmKBsP0mriOV5VCUmbiI4JGXvlbSMo0jTS3HgfzG8oCo4fa3ImlZv/TfEntwrx4DkDAWPFqi5yvoS9eWMqkeReFgUJA8cFpdeu9A8ycO4z64VRLCylqhfOcCL@C0n9yGA3DrxMMKdAGz9NVxQgwpwVc0/81OkNm/lHxX7/eqtyhb4jrurU@SjVpR997zg8olVht0DGlO3waV4nb3Fik@Wfgm7xnohitYmUlmiKh68TpnwljOeepmiAiokFvLKDyrZ4DJa791tei4LfmxHglvw4iZyqipk30G41yWNr0xJFiFcNuINvRZUkINPqU43VbmOLDNGm2o9wb9VaAq8hoicUglE2M2RRIb1HmPYe0RnywJdBOdYFuiiauPYKdq67EPduGnLMvPFsszr7iacebA4a0Oq2edYATl@H@DTSk2568U3SVDcp0MhCSXstffK874yri99UhzCwcxlhbtw6gXi6miGJK1NsEGsA2TeSxDqssLxGKpIDyROtc3dHMioctMrhLEB0gRtx5Y8Fdw18YmWB6oIOQYkKZCx0KWmoyoXfB3HlHMpKQ95l1s4J0L6tXZi6nZiOZecGN9NJb/gNvAYaVFV2aSt2w4FPZucK0jjnjXoPT3sopF0TnGsXbdx3ZKU1gRrc5ervNcEtnC@uEscO0QVW@Fbc9t1Gyf78OprAitWkgYZwH6WRHkaGYVngjB74y6vXd@1oiesIGWQD@Ps5VCgYLekQNmQsSTwwl1YDXi@c/5AekCXv46TLA@Gzu/639hzvEC6eO4KE1gOrotOnMuJjL3EPp8wwWBN7jUyqqG@AExeQm8yL1W/lItSPPPbXgFOkaAkMDRcNYpwq68lg52AoHALaXPkcQejOVffm@96lQn5j9X1lxwDpIPrXktXZjFVcwU7VYsCC9RKy/XQyyifI93H7pK9TBzxyJIHKpwBoS8kTiFV6GWAMFL5du0gU5mvreeFh2JuxdcUaQBOgdwT1WI243Wy2Qzus1QOZ0UvlqQRXe5Q90WNQZwI2Ad8@JFd6i3hWOJevEcaParwOI4mGkS@IhN1KJoiHpYsJVsBtpAa0SeChK0uFfyCOReyZj74KFSuKL148Hz4MDboXS2tvAEYXCe9tDJyYfKHFbl4ABY@16pECIqAwy34sU@/K@BZjZKPBUjBL3ka2Sqed6Rsho@THFTVGZ/4MCkzc3soEt@0gC@KB@u5rsAbyVSEFsHBfeXDQT1pBHNSFb7DYhrhz6smVuPcdUeMj2WbOiZtmjqHfMrVWGwJZbXb8DI4MmR4wduqmkPcciQI2ThqPLfG0mHgqurRjlvieMNcTrVLMfvRuuInXncGsCglSy8wF6eT4NiBgxeURuMU/bjQKFlgUB7kvF/RGl5c9hI1i@YN@s7OawI9hIk6ASttqM8XWZi08iQa4ksAvZI7Xgmnmyki/aKYBmkDZoZNLYSu25CEPXRkV6ASBgeWTIY5bVcskNIcsBiLXsbKhSxvy5UlhwL5iHOvyX0ufFy26bB86csOMxsn1C2rGc1tCpeEg1uJFiHsdTnUycgq2Nfm26YwVH@VwIV7yrdnVqMKpwdtSWYwh8X9ZipGjCDJk4VQNDvNhFxVHTD@6abfbpZBhKqF7VafG/i8XrxmedZEpWClZS6FJnWv7snljhQ5oUbObAWmTdmK1V5Ki6Qzca6KpeV0UdicUM/y09J9Twqz8UIi9HTDgL9du3f06j7UT2NJeryAThV0caY4CsTsLO8Q4vKGnVHUBdoN@0MWiKjjlxnH5kuBFpniwFpDCXHfyGYFyb6KUeYdUFKdXtWg1CXlXBFwcP2OcrzLGSHBb2uSM6wMVuVzGJOBmSmnq5ig8QEyM4Ey1m0z8KCRKwmsrtrPS1WVZUK8n7W9LKkh9cpHJuC7Cf46TWPxNvvZBTvKNtAU1Mms8mLwZH/ucuc0c@Oi2JUbE@p8G3RBskkgkae7Fihbluxhg1sKFbjwnXRKhsSoBm7OnC6@YcGn7nesAp/wZJ2bbGwgQHWOtWOByK68iHNXuQDppVJ2f1LovGcrbIXITlV1HWzlVQHGkg2hC@hdiCqWSHJaDs09ICegcXoZsqJZZlBVK4Prajx4IJ5whDm2xjcumMcBSTmTeICyqSc2UV1ZjMto7bROA34KRUIipBdJ3yjBMPokJ@hOLcsgmrZIJZVIJmrF0mJCRj2o/QabZq7tmoaJQsd0p8E2bjdJFJavoYNJlrtpGpF8yHIX1J2MSGCiHwgi@AcZvBS1rhHHw4ZHyqd/B7FbcWiXyT7j8kDrpskr3ogPwfC0EppFAPWsmsgiivSINXFzwgjaRGifwx1Zxdk8hrtUkd196sbZovId91qkeBXpNwm5yCLoJVWjJBA1azX8Bj9@yUvmV6xNxithmfQ4ckoqq17EDAEkpzuKISiQ5c2/CUV1G3ZVL1QiSKyQwTTpAWzvS2NvS/rGdIcsZw6@iaTBMs3nZHKcwkWsc4sCMgL0xpLeebs3jx7ABdw73Gt0e/cXpT5cV94NpwIH3tJD19EanVY2KYTrrNJ5wIiT4bgLqhM/uGFOWN2CvRA50ZgQz6jWJ07jlU3JhVLjR0B@4dsNZq9@224tnbWt0l0E3AM5Q8XGlKx4tVjkdPiaNc6HQyuAgA8HpxlAtCF1laKK4UBGiUtPW/D0gPX@uSyQnI5PY0NhWPdq3XqMhfAIt0s3kcPU6lZ3a8gCfxpHUBNBlU4uKYbA@8ml3c3Z5/mRp9VLRnpXG5M6sOAai4jpam1Os9dwZzkfa2kwAmf@Ei4Se3OXBiyCxrkOVVi7mkkNcWoDWlE1FZlL0JesilPA78g79ntYjXVVmwa3DxIffPYEgUgSKDyegIR1edRHHsfjySo2Dr3KODG0RWf8dORmPBdCP/ILTWDDVzbCQADKkfkpqY92SBcYUEM1uO3G7YfBnfEN8iJKXTdJWBJ7zV2yYN6M3YDabfJj0WfpiWM/3bx/XLe5nnwgbUt2awCzCIcNOInYkF1vBb2XoErCtRKk3b0gjv24XybebuzJAAM3xgXWoS7dpQ77HS4aUnW3H8eHcyhQDjU8MjRpSEQhuRt@vLbQi8fkXM4pr0IEHqThWi@MNkhxopYdcYyz8QwRVsNVj8ITacBA7YAdjFfXDlyOb03Y5V64ErziTp@zPGuSPyThUKfKE6c2W4g@02xAmEdcpS5/s0B5sT9rf7wYp8ErkHnx2J8EcKBtsjoKOcWsVeGh3/kzyloCUj9egjue0ql1YTHv8Vn3zmdFThzhEFi@wYAuX1Sb2JPRMyOmqtAFG2PEQEFDJKY9AurNDYXNRBQexIfKL@pVZxXG1hV5U1LkCRNRH/o2VlBV4Yn6XX3qxYpg43IgC5IW/YZi5MOtB/1w2NK9EEwJMs81lJP2Q0Wg64Ziy2JTxRn5f3LAEdZ8iK1xjSxG48R4JZkAKQjJ21bnJoWjqoCE7ZrqcJlM03hXPFkSdzuwJtkkoKPy156SQfYlVXdT5kV@AF4T8cAFxF5V8X@XgFj5y@MijpVfvS1BRSNfWhreDe@X1eLI4CFoVaC@ewdPyFWqzzUtfbFlcVfXkBCPi9MDxFFLSX6zUQ2x5iqPRHZ3IgnWFWHzmtwgRUsRHlVVUsAAylGP4DXsalUNZcjLq0xHBuYy69Ka4OgfBHCpP89jzn1h/1ciSycT2pGnBijD4iXOt8AgwFgTZQNZNZLGUGpdNSEMiWaGi9rk8YlG7xCBOz@umCSee4ftpTFekOaDr3h6KMeWR7@IPd/uRfHguBhGGmh5NXlxViAeSxv7j6nmu/wDcQYCyKK9arxQFBFLDdWeQZueMNEEfroVkXGd6G4UBulYO2kMhwdrZOPEid41IBUyp/IY7oAMypcKWZa11OW98fHi9fuWX8mdoj0RweiUvJ4lb195sFNQFGEjKw606R7dCmYa5obKFLhEVsoyLjE1X4y1pS3LPJIKGrtEX2hq6m0zs5iE9vGo5/mGYBMYCZll0lLjCLqxVUBUdZnqC8GTFTlWK92fmuzWNSE71AAr1ZQ6igsd2Oddmk3ImeUfundBkHzmbn0PhcwZCJSp9gBPD93jKpt1RHj5eu1NZW2cq@vjhsMd95Ho4@rV48hZ84FSTYgMXnVYgmSdYhYSlykBzsL0R5OTyowkYzmXLojcK6jwKBfzD3kVzxviear5SSNMybJDWElIvj1ZVLKcSGVAD9ySZwXlSvUFAXxSQ3CsC9Gk/P2KgFC/62ZD8i@dKJni0Wr95QpyX5WT9EG/7qK/AL9rFAgwJ@hVXjuL5uVZPkyuIRNgtKlapY5I4SFPVufYSecvlSqgAVnjlSS/Y8qHUzOdnIWeCZRL8dYYFVnvoRgEykaSY929OOQg/bfB0l4JSoy0jMp0ab3LctfQlD9B5qBp6bYp8CPFJ53cfiEmkmr5aZ9bDvdwfNWgCsrBKAIOOq6mSHoBBuOBSBwsSo4XCHOMKswtknNGVJdzv0BdhES8i4ztDFGyKN08gg/wVB2KMwzsi5oMTnXcFBusZJ/HR19ByTRAL/f6VEtd2A@PdCga5rPi8gz@VpUNeSqSl96qMrumGmrWthGWMCPieNS7uLzypUEUDclP9LjSzFQDVy18VrPNLWwesLg0sSWRsGxdhkkVW5dE2Ernz4/yMsSCPLGdQEvYWBVVlMpTvdCqDFEvoni9gk0JZvJZujTrKWh5gr4ZEJ8A8RDjcmVXt2ftp4zVL9XmmpZ5DjJwNg4ZPovL8eZ3HjuYkgT4VTRx2usDk1Cp9A72Z/TbistENinslEbxGpiz2hEhfWouHHogD9OY3vm58toxIegdy1YlqpOI6rVdE04FZpz2LYaykPJUi2Sohnqcu5JjI7hrOYbG@6eD54Eq2SH9Ts0FACq7lfzxF8RllJCpcdioJM7v1HS9WFosZXOMLapgmi7C7d7AMD8rfdlqXEl8GMfTqrT2vIkInld9BEdOhiquXMlQpauUYPNYj/Q2OlFOI8S1gGdBRVxv0KWqtW01UlUWMYMv7Ue62yOGxNqUoGm2@fI9yw1T9GQXkMVZJdF9MO4Fj3CqK2s0E9Dk3/Byri/OF7VBhDyfBP2iVfBgFgb2l25U2dV7cxpMLkmKx2l4/kS2z2feU@MXK6u7wm1aEq5whdqM281bnljNlxT/obPLh3QYBAIvAaPR8BYrbg9ObjxK3b56DXNgAGASiXCOfuxW4wPA@GcpAaMVkjX43NAA0tuBDzWn3qCCixm/61tX212e5QxVzIVVRYrhbvFFhTymind/5EYVooTrIBobQH6LxmPGW2PzKlFtlRfqaR2kob2I2qmNaCWQafdoPajzoYFp7VEC21DBUo2nmsUNH1Opb9RoUD/0ncVn4Y9Tm1MSPqUUMFq3hhApQWwXma0fgJeommk7bsRXhLvEbDm07@BNuasqmGnJqFNjZFZ4K08tLL31HBI4atNIKqN5gP7I1rHyH3xFvnCQgaxjJVNNETOrUVd1QbR1cJnGNsY9tX/hXXe9yZ067RG@As6yJErW2jJyg0pyn5Kxv@t65FyUxcYbhvMu661d/RfoytSobhCmHFqUaHfJ2t9iijGo9u8c1JvUqWFcK4PBHMs85fgshma9qo2nwi4GJuIRyxasZguuF7QMyUhMJSYIt3bLWVlPPFKMeyx1t3nY1cpyGnlwGgHACVbX3g/Num3qMO7K4NqF9DVTiQDS7p6uq4vHa2hm6A73d1usaHXTqZltN69jXk/zOBXJoBtStjeiqFkF9OxCFDyLDDY0Bb5Zn8dZv11liCcvOqsYBt/Ft/3LHc1ZsUN6kZRFiBQLRc8NMiyndry3F/HHppkMt0WUNQuIMtZ2MXVHKhaZtr1NhbdpFSLNBXi1Wx2gtTTpo3FJkirG415W8thP9by76R/WDpXTvNVJH7l4QwpsW51n8qjxbZE6FiStm6N6hwh0LyQPtsqtO0yF9bRTLX4wYb@0AZOERQzhIDmscxcmWJC4XfvRrOZhsvQoX0s5@a8gpbaoNiUhaXQRryBCq6YYWrgduKmxy4pLMWoedd/iV5CS9yhIOZxNmQSC5gS3tCXApQ9MWVWjYUHCGqlclhFt3UUT6@@7TMnr8MFUgrY8AfW2i0d7K1UCGJgiqnMgV9EsXU6WFd2m1oGaiBEI1wRIE8fnfqLBcDW4tvZRhRO4EKzoEdHXTXX4@ahGcu@uvkHRUPy88lNWtcqHiLDotn@QBd21NEOcvTpfU/8iG72RZbvbBorFqDq7lXP2s1o9Gt7CHZwFypZRW/V4CKQV75pVV1Qw74T8tbR7BPy13YkG9ccN9W17txEVGzBVlUDDNUTfjHrVtVtwJtsv14LKK@38ALAtq724F1j3yzdt4AQXtKFCyKsbSQNpo9wZtkWARgGLfMRpemZ04mW3KUwjKxB38sJ1qRT1ASzqYeATHbFeUFXEsaa7U9KWBWJj2USLKSDbzPcmkL/Ald0PG0A0tm61TkwY4x30840rLO8Mp@1dXuCKA63z8ILhK90CKL5hJe7a0F2SwUonI@3aOxa3YWVu43XlmRoAueLTWlGPB7YdyPFOqUj1YWc12/IMDSSisUyrQHYPsTb5OyT0xBxxD1xN3X2eBE4S5dEsWbO2Ck6nHvjSjJiHX@YVlFeXEr5yabh6GbkepzbOOaEXQrS4qFbwQ7TBFfKXMZUh4Qs7fdeEU1vvsQSQClBhucW0kQbOqj@aibgepi1CB6iAsGdcGhhA/vwCVFjpmLQpcdNw1irayShT5WZE5RY/TeInGk/ZvbPi3T30kstnVmzS1QIVUvR1itjtlxF6FVFbfniKF2905wfK60U0j1rAFHiKstSCu7rjodm5jKO/MaVbz0FD/sZUqvYUdowkzdvSBss6tbPC2gFKeKwKKlKqFPLXtDWrar9QggL0WB6mTYywvhpk6RnvFQucwQhk6dqe8ktE0X70Kv5Itos2X6GduFWbUZ9gN0DJoipDGwIw73UDipVW3B3rfwUoWfLnJgHgo2Vwd0M9L/Mq2k9@R7qqdkZStc8D8d4JD/UGYAOx3z2adYzPRQliB8Wq24FECKAAGuZha2k8Qf26pI5rFI@7AUVlovpW2Ctrr@52aa6hoqfcsqlkiTCQa91qznQWHzzuJnfTFKNqEPtQUSWqWYl5QBTe4WtEsQLHS1vta9FcZND4vNPGIqd52iFIOQ1R3C1@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@CitfAiZrSKqiovPtRUdG0@7onTh6WQsClNJ@KimaxROpCu0HF1I9qjepPFUBEBRUdEWI9IPEfItLbts7tK56Sb2NtXvt3hCpNm5hnvpbNIpGwVeB8VMMpVJlCFX7szVPIdjtOEnfRlDM1f7OUJvUjktL3hYbI2pjyQVIAbRM/OR4a/YZmjy/3BlobZ0K5B0gMubIpBb37vf1WP2Lnyo02lvXgSvrgKfrndWxf8ZT23@MKS6F@2QQ9801UPnGFEBGu@C3mB1c0Emg1VHBFm39/wVT8@GAq411Rmf@Vqajo@wuqklVSuafs57si@ElV/hpYYnFv@ZO/BhajKuumKoP1eqiKpgIXq31TlfxQFTWcBCytG1XRHrC3/GFJQt@MqzTVomxvwtW008GAZcJmssyQmsYJHlxJJn6m4YqoykksrgdXwhKu2AyY4QrpzOek@VKC7rxxZf9r7dNuXGG9XbjQPnd/URtdsehb@zhVtq2oohHY@pTTcKUMU/lK@7xhpR7pNlf4Clb4X9bhS@BKiB9VlWmjf3elNnwwFW31sUghWEPAD1/O3Uwl@joN8OVmKn98UhXEj1VVdHRU0iEk2tj8S/GThdfhET@u3X1MURVtIkFia/YfWHmoyhZtENDd6qefy7jKErC4T/WTNMyumfzW1dWxqspdP79x5bOq4m5cIe2vdbm7/git@6X8SV/JH6uqaFTX5I@26mYjK07Fe4OV9FlVecsfwQrG8rYVMWjsPmpTUnmPM3@SFf/ASh/NNlQpO34JhzOxrbEFnbmSH/z16kTaDkaYr473EbAk9cjVihNd0fgT6sedJV45CVdSsz5Ba@@kSB4mc@Jal8RPSx/dxU9Q0aVVUSHfJK8QBhxmy1ZRSQ82Xm9MgVdZrRgUFabc86RSvgo/lZ82TZH4fEPKh/jRqU5qWqnCubSZOQzZS7EuRNls6MaIigqCygHpYin2Dzzxu2VdcU/8dspvrRoY3niCWrjxJBIeJx/1xZ2mfMrXPOWLdeKC@O2jfMSxp8opKJ@8bVZO6YYn0/ZXzqZd9qFKEQuVw32cQSkdS5HzUT7rcNYpEppoKsKjLN6Vc4QPDnB99n1Ak9KWXMRYCnKUpVaNlruM8zz6NDQ5xFLapQlZv7m38PmspIBHX7EUbfBW7cm2aiRNrqpMqk5egaXEizT@uG7RuVPq8nSBvNVouZDRPm2uS@IRVnR8r4jpHlXMXSLAtIFGJCU@Yz5qj2tnNCHWAgljjzZeHqw87zSdRj4dmr3Eqzz3U566QwTR@YQIayqOEqzro9EL31TV19y2LtcgKZu1fbQkli1gXpqTt1liMofcYQgPXdd@FAep17C4SrJh9fXWPc3z2RSCtZU/OYr8Kns7ESZpnz@0/a46ChTXedwjg2lOXhCTAiULrBe@G5K8GYqG52@Gov3AaplknLPY/JNOT3iS7t3HiJ@VlGzUVG1@1MbChpeduOCOIys@OsyqfN1V8lqQoeERskvWXnf/dN3hqTqe4IBNis4lybnRJH6swSCY7EOnek0s2MVnivUntRsahEkqkQTbG0iqNInoZtDWLoLhwRN363bN29hBZvf2i/Ppu0vxR3NfF9Dt5c1Stm3mbWrJy8NS5kc3eRysb7hEGuN@3ns8yIYvm1Lpkli5GkexqWsdySJA0eyicRQvQIlWBz6s64NzYaD2qX3C0/WxbR7gPcThUrCTTKDmTZrIpKj3Uo5fc5T@Fj/uzVHcLX7Mf/1K/mtQyaAv@VWyQurn4rXOirma6v04vQ53IhlXnfKj/qUtSzDtA4EZOskI1h@zBmB0mF1ItoUnjB7JgBcgz4@tsOmUtaDJQ98eTOEuOuJFiQFQQS7EV38avcLH9zQEWV90CO6oTYvl0mGBIn3zq0GVrynKSFZNMUZvt2k2qaJ54WSTKtr0Eh599UyqQFKmhrC1FEpaDTzs/mnGLc28nsomNsPnNf5mMGwV2vCUzjW@TdICo22kW6Mq6S1LtQfdxE@3oyHFUiBc2uXB@oMmWT6/S6Oc70bWpRuhcsu2bAPWvDdU2pBKDtpUcrc0yKSeaHqS7z312nWS2Io6HqtD/VkXzV6o9KgWAsDi7hIt/8WQeGoXWHqQJYTLz0iWOzRcoTZAtBLtV@1kIcsgbXZ0Fs9@kBCSiZ@oEYQynR2V9lGlvYd7rnfzRzWVoPMJYtpUyFcduN01lXE7MgS82FTiVDPPc5dDfjd1ngDBCd0oPuX4duIpohLvWYhqHFjbMcRMuYW6NMGrXNTqsTIeRLhOm3jF71/xKavcRz10nZ/iNPVkhZUVYBlHNQWE0xIrFwssppK1vncmEVWRAtKu/vtFhMPj3pbiLtnfnJgoec0tYyoTQFaBXRoCDV9tI1L7J3mNvKam6tBhqPNsTsjtJJRJh1u6t0DczqUqqQaEbAPZAy556SRQuCjpMLh7TuVjcLuIciEhNT6isTJ0ek73oIrbx6kKHA@sJrpJhn5jCwBmr6J@a7eBCKlrCShtsJEm3eu46UprN7A4a/74pPPuNteHjak0bZaou3IDptdpDmomCFq1VVOZsd9n8Qw7kGr2bW3qzaNtcTLxcfleH0fXUQ9ZZyPpTBZioWgXChnRSVnne12UJGuZkImXbRohP17K8l/rn/AKOgBtXjrc5nRwkgjTWc@yKBin5ccuYTpUq/VN76xSrcBl16hKtYKHCaA3Y/GSZ09X2bb1kYEm2KOzoz47/ct06ZG3N@bvvE7TvPe8dAbOuufglPilgKagQwP1NqvMjba7gANQXBP4reN1TPUbyE3T9dOa/d54/TNQz7sh6uvQZnz0d9NmNVizFVZIMtoK6t1hlRWwXAqohdNbsVbpUZwl6VioDsU5xFnUlbN@z7Weysr9VxNAdpjDV5UVBagWN2ubCK632bKoWqsizrvcFbRr4qUTflVm715tTKh5tC2enyBZbiZ5lm23EQynkTZyZAcjs4wlzq/xN575oS33/NAGuAOP8YX/1MNNH@0pdQwr8PWxNUQHguD2Gnm16mzGXQs0r@yapnUVt9SJgbaxRiRWKshqts/QNulq68ono6swTdoaqqmKc6etVxOLdjJK0QBGtvObdCSMVWgktZUhtWNDRVtrYAqteRHp6w@5KMITXj5m7dYBlD1x4I7o5rm9e1mpPJvN510cJEKLxlU0VE0ux2fzCd6HpTOiuvaFnJ/zaa8HWpzVVjRBu1@xXOvu9d8jcAoVpxG4ey@NOvxKs9qPArIEq6xo@wbC4h6B47ZPZUXUyDa9wZXUXv8QQwg7zW6biA@aKRjPCEa8q7YKp3qLIZs@LqeGeWw2osejjmg9TC0zzoeerc8e60aqUdE2jngVnY5IMNdpO6nVyr/Gs8/BFkrgov2cKW/mxEnjyHbGILREZwpbFyjFRwyVh7c8XSB4sU59LNdOQtHIrsJ6/RVv2a02@AwRrfv4xXTzlqJDBMhBrTWrchu0LA3LnNFG7XQklrpA6olz/RPaoqpP0vbn60F8d/OWZZyla6yqJUELWGesNeyfE7YqrnCfTUsDy8zWbdq8TvYb/gUJOiB7mHW59/76ucH/bzdTzSBP0lOR3G46qIYX66o5qgcEs4tTbK8ZtMQeN51uaLQl2xicr00EsqsNBFtIdtZ21qlW/XxGu4qkRNK8ilqv2Qb4tCS7@IsOl9P4lhomRR2/W9OtjyZQ2Hq4Gaezim08e7PCXXXbcRdWdArn@WYsMKisYxazjjXTGMK9hVtDdDoeYj77hbudQxA1xQlRLqoOqq2qCZNYDit8LLzg3kbR@t1ZzoYrzmY6yFpR99bW6uS23U/XDu6ofKiDEnZT8trdn@yMPDUSkFgsp04KciBYtqPPVTtq9w4HzXTq8GbAgYQDJLT22Vpus1kp0t3VFduFYraKyYiq1xklQNArKiiThe0XOyisPznrKRK5Z6deOqPHTK1cKpjclKW4KODWkC6cRcnxfObQJbpuqaIau4aQTc4TBkjkfvb0OQR33GOciGbpDjBFpb8ctmermY53ubcFO1Fiqw1mO8vw2WpGZt90WK0/ipUgUWpogS77gJG7l5p/TiK4Vqj34RDl7jigmzaeYde50EPnLpeqKSsokLaaiU7baCLitV3Ttjh4CbMethZk9MNp7abmuaudFS8kKjqCAlGeT21OBunTvu5qbTnHaF4jliD2pxQaNrRgRELHietQYzRa14Y5TWzbBrCVy3m8@zPeBCq@ORNAjgiCkEcV0KyQCg5H8@FbPmLRe/7RDg4@bdrZ6axOCMCxpsb5nNtuhifG8wjhhg@PrNYyRDNYB/uyDeG4GARWR9rqYIJ0lzm91SAv7Q6wPtBL2zWIYh3RTCTr2DMko9VrW9U25/DOwfdAqthlJ607pSdttnGQRpEvHnYTl@BbOvvZx3T5ZkxtH03H2Kh/gRrw2iw3t6TfEeB0nlLedLJ4uc8Lu1iupSO@tTVP@9AgTE5HqB@7DuDWSN5ZJZRVEIapnc14atjEUw/gjx8AXZcd1@G07eiIeSP4fNcZTVXbwbzK9Bp@JBtqdxH0UJ3ZadGoSbeoE63Ds2PunnZ@PbuzxEy1KbIoyes0OmxKwmsqJutgxTch8hpIuffMGWsQXREvUa8m2GEa7RkguyCxdp90i@2O8rQpyzn9mi@7QdGeeU0fgazL9ly9edFVEJfacPyyoyFgdNq7BPXxQedsTp39rLOjiJhEttDOY9zn0H4xO1tIJ7LY4W1xgr86MH3Wetphs@I/Y2ho/dRRF/Ar6cGkPbPRDgfkYQlblazrxpocSOGqs1BBNMlyOwZayQR@B6a2sVY9uJTGT56pAsJVJ9LaWCoKHseFThiKDWDX9jLZGC88sqrWq43lGgnWXGp55jA@ivVX0DFDMBZtewrYS4y7acutziy5868G7qQg4j1upyEc7YMf0POwrXOQ5Qc/yJJtqtgciGl89sTrwJECpe/qZNaWD@0ykodOd25h3odRk6a9EqHGvzW1GPrRV4tHPDQAU9LGauRNBxgq72u@3I7QRiDq@DbyUi8QrTMf3k6M9DqHNh0LtawaZlc6bKd38PGkrp0qNnpTr4LFsBFtHcuKejhPja0c/tD4gEMbbtCiyuqTGXVq57LdtIUl1QGfq23rPlGY91dO1uOXYKf3IEd4IY2r982JSkZ/7JBCr2O9VThR3SzOo/fzJJibmnI6UirZ78C4dPZzT14ZNqtdm20UQptvqm/boXP0SA9HnieOyZOcwyed9a@jNSvorqZw0Qlp0E1EKOF6QtibnQmto@LxZh1tX8tISecYaR34OZ1WcJ4XKLXppF3@HBr1B7jt9BIXIQsAKh6n076MjuMH@dj1iyK4OUJYe2Bk1THtSGudvlnj6VXoVEQqMOzIWp1jZPe3M55FRg6VfoYASmfnz65db0EbJ6tP@VJ7XZXepk@p@KnuDLk@1n1hmnZYeQD6fog86JcJKBf0jx1mDlgNR/QSSP0EIxSy2vl1lH5kP33TKWodCQvoQ4CSfgWD1/nphCe4nPW7A4JWTjO8xaYoms56LzqCv2@7TsaCDQGUXod7qPHRlA7yvqWx6cD1qQMtJfR0UF@3HQ37hEuRGF7FK463XTMbRMPJf3l17YxPHsqJeyPIOusBqx4nDsarkUw6r68dRsUq0m2MM4Zt6rR6vaXOpoNBgRDJtmz2ZGcI6@RHTJDSjkGyDs1xXeVrvuXOo2l/LsrHmV90jKNDAAG8ffrubcSzF7sh@cPZUUVwZR0fMnQ8Jeaw0/ERv167P/FAmQnYJZFyqa5zY3kcVrfb8yf9TocSty6WFnF6nS0d9ANjQEPtF8iUjrzr9itjkuh/1AnQ/Kkj/IQFqZ9F26tDJNmDWazIqdN/vZeijeMIsiqL1BNcDO1DltHpbFFn3U4dnpPtyPqq3Zw8IPh84jW2x1EkYFyHG8Z@kDsXsKnDE9M4dW2ygnYbIRyT711AqN9JoY2QETpXwokDqK6ox9qKTpxWmM3kyd4qsrMYMEQVlqEBKdhxwsn@pRaq/c4NQQJSmOtu5BT9HhO9eLrQM9onYPXSaJv5dNw94Om1MDiiCC92Tzr8auiQ5HRvey9VpyBbQKshL32lbX46f0ktIbmx/RH07/l8Kx066CRpAh6TQfshBIe4dbAdQAJdcxz9EgoCmvRctGVZv5XCoEHHEormCZTFS84UhjVQJ@JGB9WO58hfHZ6GckPaLEE52kzYmpp@LYN@oUzRxgTlOX5G@z2nNo3oXF3eVBVG2@ygM66S6ujKMRpY0UF2Osyt2RjaDDyxqqIEmI5uqVIkLPUxVaCyI7LdJemszq5avzo6ofFTOpk7QMbT7WjQBi8irKOOGngNVui3@0DToDtJe751ZLesotNYi5rmyYY1WV@Sof0iIJdYnqI6@qH6n6o0zkMSkVv65QMaUkc6qVA5XzmakzrWEPqpSqu2FmgZJxc5@rDO/qVCs4Yr4Tkexu507rQO9FWbhcfEk/yy668c75OTk01DEap2xuYCTGC@2s/SgI2@dMaE7dRP@Sks6DAFgUb1lx1@hRAmOwAm4IwOS9YBmfrtN16be1MCwnkn7IDj2Tfs8HVNXhMHm9Yo8Z89/0pIde0HLluy49k32ODaHClNFfq5ada@deUB/SYFndvBow7bmu1ysM1B2qdhG0iUSLsONvXF67f4HNZIsKHD1rYh2Ne@FoQUQGotRN5Ozf9GFknf/PY/vv3xV7/7ze/@8O2Pv/32N9/@@OO3f/nHb7Zv/u7vvrm@@acf/vlXP/384/d/@pd/@Jtv/vW7n//w/Q9/@ssfv/mf3/z8hx@/e778lz/@@8/f/uv391@@/eO39xd//vGHP95f/OG7@zt//O7ff2df/PTdj/bnf3z7x68u8Hz5l/szf/j@p5@//719@f1PP3z86M8//uXPP//w5z/c9/rxX953/enP3/74832Xv/z0@a1v3x/4@S8//nB//3d/@enn7@y7v/7tv/1m@9NP35/2fr/939/x4V/98w/Y4ld88dOvfv/Dr/7tN//wb3/77T/@7p9@a1@9H@X7P333zW//z4/f//zd37Tw94Mf/1lf3Bf6m3/79a9//d2ffv93//mf/x8)

Compressed string, along with count of each string ending with `yl`, was made using this:

```pascal
type part=record
      name:AnsiString;
      count:QWord;
     end;
var s:AnsiString;
    c:QWord=0;
    a:array[0..50] of part;
    i,j:word;
    p:word;
begin
  read(s);
  p:=pos('yl',s);
  while p>0 do begin
    c:=c+p;
    //writeln(c);
    j:=0;
    while j<i do begin
      if a[j].name=s[1..p+1] then begin
        Inc(a[j].count);
        break;
      end;
      j:=j+1;
    end;
    if j=i then begin
      a[i].name:=s[1..p+1];
      i:=i+1;
    end;
    write(chr(j+ord('A')));
    Delete(s,1,p+1);
    p:=pos('yl',s);
  end;
  writeln(' + isoleucine');
  for j:=0 to i-1 do writeln(j:3,chr(j+ord('A')):2,' ',a[j].name:20,' ',a[j].count);
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 1103473 bytes

[View source here](https://hqfot.surge.sh/d.txt)

By far the longest answer I've ever done, and probably one of the longest (non-Unary) on Code Golf. Definitely longer than all my other answers and questions put together.

Comment: "probably one of the longest on Code Golf" [no, I don't think it is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161757/print-the-previous-answer/162080#162080)

Comment: @hakr14 Dammit, forgot about Unary....

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 16071 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...Array(27598)].map(_=>'isoleuc|methion|threon|glutamin|alan|prol|phen|leuc|ser|val|glutam|glyc|histid|tryptoph|argin|aspart|lys|asparagin|tyros|cystein'.split`|`[a/=20n,a%20n],a=0n,[...`-}Þ÷...Ý¦û´`].map(i=>[i=i.charCodeAt(),i-=i<127?34:68,a=a*188n+BigInt(i<0?66+4*i:i)])).join`yl`+'ine'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LFwHU1vL0vwr5JxzzjnnWMATOQgEQuRQYIMNOAAOYGyMEUJCKAECEQVUTf@w9/Xyvrp1DUjn7Nmd6enp2XCGNdOayR790LghckzX2/ff/sz/dmVmtUdFReXq9Zq5kLjkxNSU0I6oUc14CL8IHprUafumehZH@wyDQ7qxRcOgvo8/BrRTBs3o0NiiRqsZWxzX67SL44N9Y4tv10726RenNdr/v4g/5noWB4cmDUO9iwb93LhBNz64qNEPqLsnxzV6w6J2bvJ/v2rUh4Y5vW5ysWdu0tA3NBYcNTmuHTL8Z/E/7ZrozLiYsQhNIP/tiNBk8nfV7/9ELuEId9hdxD8xy7VOnPJcAUdiEG7a5QnrONM0wgTHwARulsd78A7H/PAnVnGLy/oqrLXKWeMc/zjEN3FUyXUbVqrlcnkR72fZrrNpEjtwjsKB@9nBSjHhMT8R/wawiV9Y74AFK3Lqhx2f2WBsYTWFf1pxjgc44rWNyfgSK9ZwfMW7uHR24ppNefCiF5NcwZ4kd2UFcPPqveZcXGB9GK9R0XCPiK1LniJhK8FTTGEo3gfhsAwfw6fkiW27G9l1a37fRLI4ygLkZCkKv7Ty3JCOy04cyQ02K8XYBC/Mo@Kp1@UkpsjjPFziFkd5hZyKE8/yzKduzcETucyuucVZgI84bkrF7iA2dFgXrzzgYghXeXgNLMV6nF/qEt5jO1RO6gfZwC0OquS1FI@h8ZVyj2fc1rFPl/K6KKdTclORNizGJDbxlB@EHzB1l/TKNX5NwliCjwHpPhEafJpqGhUHXrEtln68l4dpMUXJbQm@47vYQn1CiuAVj1wHyGWimMtzaysn5SUnsBJX8fiMd2F9yWLHHv7MixGXdMX58hxvNWO7mihwlsipGsexH/6O4wBf8H0BLnypxeMSXvABJ3HYl4vMntYa3BAP9tbucmwWJuCvoXp5UhOD1yH8KyoO6xgwwNrIC37W4TgZlyW4GgiJ5FNOO6bkhRC6mIOlDS/iSQkX93BApM9kp5zX0x5HejxyeKvYx2MBDuLi@dlTWDiccHUn05LOxgmxaEaS9BytlZ5xR8zLiXjhXMafENjSsZumrY2JEncFbPXs@m5IaA8vvcRJth7OpRkxp4f6FdXRj6vDox3hctYjlymNnQtyAiu98yLXGbj3zayoVdZMx0d5GYFJngk7V7e40qfwPoDu@YG/2gLcTcsjTWRcKI@BETc1cBvwmFeAlV6cl6YxAj4b5CIPX7OX5a4VP9IWNY15DLTb6gWDWOdwUjVR1ajHHwM7s@6Hr3KfuCze2gC29RRVXrVclCAnMw1yl@1PcxxNTWAjCmu1E7TfAU40437auslorBbhrl@umrEa2LuEg85aA/072B9e3ihuuMtxVI2jMvxKGMOGL/7Io7wE5Vbq6nBai2N5KJbbLHGE5SbAJka5xVETe@3JScbOWO2ivgBXcjkiFnjHtJk4xZac5clFMuFy0LKE7QwfskR7UFyweNnFxzRG6Tm@hg1yiHZ4osgCFUV@WXDFY3sAe7WVeK@Vk7Ri3MVE0sc3fjT4q391cyG2phJnGLM4lQd5JcisOG3MYlR/wG@O/Fd@83SknMtTIu76yAHHlQUwd0/yWT/y8QlrZB9TG93g6Z0dwW/x1uA4aLELOxyOkTFtkvtkcS6JQx8XLw7G3O@2gEL8W4iTk3kO1gVTv8bPUCqv82Slb8OM6vMAPvlXFX7Q6Y9TjP/LTrmXV3busoIscpK6PBfQM1bfg29kpTt868rlnXsNJROpreS0g46CUJqQ8Hkh3r0tONcV9aY38psLPOGxZYoM21uJezbpxn5CIu36jOucIiFc@mhrTypH9jLfnE7eFG9kqlbO0@U@Qd8h1jxcjRN6zno68oQ8eYbVBDF16uWiBNaU4MCBmpR2uYmjST7itC2pguFibkwuWtCNzspDI5/@nUxjCVUX/MIVnBUz@Iuf4fi2MFKH9616bGlx3kCWWCGud/AvHa4UsvYlHyoXDKFDOesWq7@c12FjrEY/Lw/haeSLu1DSt2UkJJ9h6E2uMLDRh3qx@eClWs7wQ0d4H4kpjCFs4y93szSlQzGxBff4UQNzCH4U9HP4tia4orGB9fwWXBriEkpxQgN7g7CbXFUk15PwaORSPHiQxzm5SsLfDrKtGfvZ0514VGwJ2yLxcQpTfFlfMZ5rxOmzwFh5KCWeI9tbxIb7iDRfWLtn8aTHYXCDXLTCKVZDPPtlwccFNnNJv9xpmuom57Djzzs@vNnZO1KQjg@tcpoiV1HZuBFXWkGBuJdHewzxffjTx14/NVbDWIrnquppOvQGf5ZxUJ4TlivP7UmTOVipwFVSQTYcmQuBk8X4EwubBme0BbZGSSgfAiv57zqtYJ3ODzIUy1Vrqy6glwzSvUjMurFLH9wOyUU6vEXlpNUB2LX40@hTxR7e@bS1juEfzMx4G6T1TQ2shPoNjeNqTG7kM0jAK7T4E77MMaZ24v0HxNMVKeauDGzX87H3@BmrYuzcF2dDM2k0/Eof@@Ng8nklHX0srY7noI1dUdMjTL8kaktBdxJRtt8YhfuU@AHG4SfCwyIPWphTs5uxlQlvZxJ@N6cGNOKmnlC3pHUT2O5c/IxLr84t7cU2HEv079PkIk5C5aasJZY@WCNG/gzhNQmHHbBW4WKhtg8HIzgcY4RvLeXhT6e4iwN0@CT2mbnFvKRp/GInj5lSbOIO5uAedeEzig931BCM/O6mnDH9Re7EMyWusjGG5ZOGvH4fUR/Xks7huRQKbK3sipG5zYi7sYpRcVaqAMFFWSU7ZAwKwdfSKkLFnIld33ICfF9eiO11nNcGiC2OD7gWYxn2fGpyNAPzzCO7y03dJCZrDg4rGDvsYWy22MVWWJTlo5GHtDqO9U88081NHb615TEL58Act1hMINr53GNaea@et1EzhYoK3Nc5eCfwzh9/W5jv7spCy3AV19oWJtYpoolUdEq22Rv1YbsHcCdhZQTXy/hHQTPy9uUqs6UXz51RI7B34LZJbGPlBPs1Jc15nLw2R2hhygvCr4m4Hr1c01o2ecnGmjzGdJIj39OB330pEC7x3Z/tfIN9ug3fJkXF8FfsEit74sLTCFHySEuaSyLHyb8vme0pjKl/seThW3mNS0nrohGv5XEWdo7puaWIHMJbbsXI9PbHUKLp6mJO9@DdbLiejfNxL72MifdyGkFk20ND6e3XhE442yblqS4Sn8uTJ33E0Sq2wcLCgvRh/BikGXZqZ/GQp9L2oJyk062npFtTNCPlGr8b8C6WpPYnCJutRd3s1nkxUfNRzhvEVjRfWYJPlfhdliiPaXSxA0fZBSEZsIt3kd1yhtSSEnYUj2uDgjqT48QaCDJjaA1JMTMtFL@DqKm@iTmXhrGQN77SVhbmjGufXuLud3s2UXwGTzK8hlGq07HWtPw@2FPEXKvluF0@7ey0Fw9t8UU020GAeIvlsY/3FcSnMTod7dGK3xLJ3vYUjvNLJH39Cd8qcKqy9Ap@ZsHpN9I@DFetXL/1c0@JTKbpEDHPiyNQngYmGbZOutPlMyMnw/hXwsFdy0N7Gv7qmDBf2nVjclZSTe743s7BnFLEWeUcjjmi7AAf@sQlzwaYNVPiKYRXadWNkgk@7W4A676E6j9xjdNXt0Tp4zDeVShgyHMYm3oRa6TYcxgdW7Vz1Bib7ImjbqQZ6@ERFfVzpKlfxLuxIJpMchndHsYRPpfDWsiI8MpzQm5v/dQCu@VgrN3D2YFPSwkxbHa9GmbG4kskn3kjF6oqGJ3hFUwdfXAVLBuyo3AbqCGK7XjOpwN28CqXM4wHZy48FaoTYokx8I4jXSs9dlkdFI3nUSInXY87f8aAZYD9ehGjf2NoOJulDiCXnuFQz3ts@Ez/XszisYhW@sI6g73t6sZmFbUtTgMGw@f8MuSsIbIgF5tyETbjz4TySmU3ToV7kMexuJTGuqDdHjhga7bcJpDMdklwnkAY66ZqB@W5a7phqV/OpihInvC5QzwZS3woZQNv96TTcCtNbPU9PXTXzjB0thYzeEM43idi3lY/z@atKZHpvOcwm3i9z8Xv1GbWOX/xqZBY5GVbZXMxOGBc/OulyynFBhiyf6jE1hmebhwPMcqP87tJ0zlvmNvEhyGcNYSKMZt1wbluAvZa8PctKl0xxfiKc1bsDfiURWu9YCs2c6gaO35Y62mcYVDt4zKNTezWNdXiWxAsvvgeRMoxT3AUri68BmXRlu8WWC99x@Pi/JgfmcqEbwkD83FdgezSHrzhftiLyiqbxeoAudJT60O6sZLLbwYiwnFTQkpyswr1i49nbnAR4PQ2qep6goO08qPtNLHPt1F@TFCdfIEj6a24c/qPMvU94qi0gGR92zMijuUu@vqCiDmHabZRM8Gw/irn8REVMcxVn9jSO22cDudpYkokJLZxIqw9GeTy6ks03uFdp0oNVFexg/NyxkFaadabQLkcze9hu3@7xZ3J6y@pGK5hrZHT3Azx5gXWsfVb4myXXqVhOji6YzhG@vnv4SjHv4aXhcEpQ1sMHpvY1ZNgHTWYh3F35tNKkW9OD6sapzhnMHydpJu/yf1ML5n584xcp2UTtq99U3y6yZe1FCwLGTTd35wlJqwduYrndYfU4h521s7urmC3US77RwfmSA8XcCbCPUfhxdILt70z1F3H@D5DUHixNVCFwwQdh7M2FJuGd71BtNo9R2HC73QawVWBregEuFpw1iHO9tb6RXKzszm3LSoi3AfHOXN5NOAPMuwdcXCbgi8z2JnsS1iuykhu9pXX/moqFVYhvOnzLC3DUO1uHOvNoTqQi0JG3jXh9zDCgKZEaYW1JbRqhMLsL1aCR/A@fi6zluZ4Hqbt7LxmD5djvYQw3udkV7cF8MmW8Rx5LsMRzrLhylkMHdQxEHapEKyLcLRxIG564RnforDfxyj/2T1DeN5EykmsRs6CeeVTB314QDheROBwACfDZbzhrBb20apcWnibl2zMF@IgB3sDRNVOHvZ989QN/XVlHJhH3CPhSrCus3tHhMRXAuwnUfuxJoIo/UXJJ6@B4gmaUjMhhfnZ4fOdjKIT9vDzkm8dO7M7rMWvRg7PJa4quvGEdLFDw3/Q4FweqjKatKGM4Re4J3SkrRfS6u1UjH9QWloBR7rC@jIY31ub8XUhIalcVy7uAXG0TNVyUG58TGIEvuKZFYI8@TapIKYWJmp/DcTP98n5YnIUNcbtFD5kyYOGY13xoaAz4qLYh71dw3ki/uXM0x77ZQz/T1oi6B4X@bzwD96Rwkb55z0x5E3vpoc/UOibAvAktvjsOrxLnclMJyisJSGqy33irSMdexnCvMWWTP5bJxhu8X1wbKhQTbH49uBLFAnsGQ/BidgcYNsOPDaz/5dhRMnVIn7FUfmz0jlpxMpkHv4OcywOpthbeZmrjy5UYe7tqcdTE0f9k9nFTNCdMM88E1t3wUS4KVbVTqN02gPeFcSEiz24GSf9uMtql1MDQ/AyKm5GnON46YZ3iL5xsgUTy/VmNbPi0ipvM8wuahtJTi90tKeKZWND0vAQLhoref1tBlXg0xBN9z46NrtiRE6T5XQwgXz6JC@xsQ34ENq35DtN9v1REkNrWtLZ52NyezWl2xWM@kGcprPNj@0scGbhiO6LxVFnB5npJYB@@dfZI6dzuGqZ08zzRlcs1QAl7gOO9fiup1t@TlQmhdPxf/CUAFUG3OKhWx4WSxOwV8CxW3pm@O3lLEnNIucjhgV8q5kahrVJrrJ7xZk16K8njNewZWirwa@0aPrAxSR3x8L4hKzyIE7WsPt08Z1W7jPy6C3rRKye2dZE0th9Q7XXl1ZbWaJvr/l0V2P30PzcTKw48mN0FWrmsm1YHDMUb3/5vSecVvRghaiNqc8ZG5mnc3fb8pLScB0dSgVD2ZnIUHuYkJtANrYNt5b67kRc1WpiEA8TTdRZrTTcz4yQ@mB2bc@PDjK@QXwVf@M6e@vr8DOU/aYqpVhgvjjy560/OuQsktg8Ek9RKGxDRJFDzopI2mqahkJ3v4/1YAnH9BrLBine7NnY78aaD1XYSQy7/Bkfm6DA/54I@cVMczM9Hczmd3HaRV@/wqFmhL42E8Lf@dc3BqCVJFZA5t0PYrkvd3F4NfCvr/jQJOdaPsqlREWcbxxu8lPL@c0FHf6cS13i2xoURQyzxNUWRUe3z@FnGNzUVOuklkteuJEfQ/r9WIivY2HlgWLpot1crbif1lIG/khXZJJE/XSPreXYviixJiTjSwZj9bqYF1o6GJ1XdYP4Poq72Fyxp2UOwtuhZUJdHyHGVnXxxEXZfB8D/EVcTLGzjDc3HkfySSfG1KxwHPURJv@qcJTOa86wM9SWQS54Jo2ZQrrxO3Z2WK5zG/BSH15XPC/ekFysRrYWUbHYs9rYPgPqGD@KMxmk7@Btri1kUfgUii@j2AwRlvxf5lKLBvTsyofyeHzozmK@OFkmxnZIo@6a0UBx53CI5sUmeLLJv16xpTCBHGuwFi2W8OD6cbH3yROL9l5ieQ/XU50j8bScHZusht7l4FP9cDKxYJqkSV7wroR1ZSqVWk45fXIIbwidx/rOp4@p/SUVPyeJ3U81Yu7xLZ3JxqfQCnHWyCsteSMP4irHSm8MWay8ej4OO4M5mXPYTx5vY8yctGbiNZ1qYcrQk@@fEKZwpXRN0wIsy0k09x8y1hl5y0Nld8cMNDyb3zfbT8efkM52xJQ7T2m2LLd@jQtKAzJ/XhNdx3mZNez4bXW/KhzwpV4bLQ812K9oZcGK5@BgAuSd0m7aDA75EH/DC@AdZShd@pCF3IXUmqf4Wo13MXIZQ0ixoMkgBX9vSZrBlzac58i9YTR@YZBMbRHPxBSdf431zCGY53nrLrabqFMotPO78ScnL9c3NIQdM9NGrmV5XEobisSHGSa1dQKkNgCOYNiL5TqEhEYi9Y1WwvGWOPoeX5xVUoy/pZUxvY3y0jG8VNEZOiL32Thf6G7hMFfbfXE4TkowgXcf4sSP/t/HQ35WI/b6y9W0j4V60yuni6OsPB1EwCfy/68lOnG7kTa1jc9lBtUxTNnnA@z4wDuPHwVtJANPD3aj1BzVEEz5JMYbAvEpPr@upWsiLoGhzqS@TEr80S13k9l4nib09oZnqdg31KzbGR7H6gaIiHkoifwpmfbewlUmWMJ/lgfKL@Zo7yxJ/pqU9EDVNUrvmYXlYhL@Zc0l6NLKxZNXwlb/4TKiVTeEL93@g8xq9iWi9LRD3KlyuzgR4YvVgFZ23VTBaPvhg/csclLm@ihRPrEbT6Wh7W0LYhujcH3CcyhJ27hA4fcTX/zyVLWLv6n9HfDMRIzgbwFF0RU9zThWE9ObhaELOCvHTV3vuFhapnE7kSfPDdHR0zVyW9/cCmMWhc6xtpgA3e3DQ7xcCStLe4lcsCHGeXFv0WwYw2SfXxjFVj5AxF32MNo2cN2UWdYZbmCE/8rBv6Aiuczt1DZM0CrrU50kynMxRkbAHbkwhPXxMqzlU3kPiK2pX0PgH9DocRlz@BpG0x3AmouVnGk2@hXGgeKYrsEUliZ0kKcU3yf48Z2qkc78cKapx/UcjXLTkt5L3rjqx1pL0gDt@4H5yTFP/xppw32xVxPpG7zQAXO8gXWgmQL4qxjzK2I4sMs@uskhlws08UGAmvEtX1a8Kw8hPXTxxoxfYkU/05i9i6P5qSjFOBJAWFzIKZl7C486mDTs@MeGUpZI1XKXmf9W4K7jaiF2bDkHJx3syT4RuI/12Mb5Ssb@PR/gaGxQ88lWXPr5BS/kthLGf@EOwte5shJmv9fkZDjSAyMb4ayvl4fpokB80mNrDPeJDUSvE@YcnKcwbAN1tQOZE/jKwI6n51xMD0TkXcoYtpNbxNaSL@bOhqIh/ErCWm79CNWLKht2ynwWYHpTZ/cTlXKWQe6qyxKLLofp6U5NJcHRzwD8oYBG8FyUpKbyl8dofO5lcO7qlFKvU2uFNIK3v7eOre6Hjst5U2h0AznOssiE6MFjVih9fx1Wxmx@0ctcvpOFO/2EXGdXku8c9Mvn5GX8LonKV5P6dt7jzOlU9U1fWyS@tJAu94tp2zVSzeaQqhBg9m/A62yqqJnfj3hZLCiYj8ZVkwKiMyNQm0f7DclZD8f1O7FM7KmM86/yupBLDr4Ua4lv3mQL9n1wPzrig4u6cD1bNqZgtSwAa5NB8DZ1BGeVRHLYLlbNZM6XypYmfCzBhy4KNOzUh3HcDzAPijuQQvNd7WR7y2ILXffYg80sXCSLPYF3OeAejsNGWngcWfKeKsWD/fx5mv28Aq@pYYMFiY3lIfomDsiupkyYzt5jPS9GLCnJgcm1dePpcv2GoS9qziakKDhXTsvxKx3f58v7W2GZq8ZqqhgL4F6Yz5YHfRR9cKiHaUCei@SiVZXHuPCNb2oIDCdmd0OxXUH7O7TDfNBlRfcyTrsJxl9QFdM9PCNiLZvK7oJltj2WUbLZp6v2o9q/prJSBSZsUWFkYSs2fYjQH9RYJnGNhPO36@7@KLVyUsqBbCp04GdxENs9fCukPVnNOjmdJUupXlwnUXe/hsSR9clkuzV9WFFz3@JKD/GN6sB6Mv4lMsVc4yaNSVmeEsaZHVf4H/V3WLQPPk69lXh3S0XDMEVRqu63ku/FXSDnneIl8dhm2eNfo/hXnhqhxW67XCYM4nWYxHCCj2Ss5whmwydxUOQ7mdzr5S46qJODMFLVmRphqiRtfONoTguG03FGAdrSo2Yj5CwVe5O8lUWlOPV1chaa3l5K7WJ6y@T7DEI2caKKyXD23x3zNqN8FsU0@iqW6AStH5HnZBQ5iyhwicWzFF7r7sdeeklifxl@lCspE5uBbwXlTO27lAAen5gqtngfTqRtibeHj7HST@zcIiF/NyrXvdlinOLovYnymMth2/CpQFyJJP8msqZXvFlq@RtHxfXMrKS@o8QxmGaW4smup4zu8wRqGDv2Etui6G8yBh98SrK8lNcRqq0d7OknsSvGXDWtWKJmUkrZmrOPF6@yG@/FMhOSIedlGj74gGmjHqtpg2oN82OGdkmrpkEnpwyNIXTS76XJHtj0eCxppGxfTZ2T@165qsZnasiydLw2xTb5NmDLt1iM9TB3hCs/0lZXOO6DOzi2UGypReywG0@5eF1S3lGa2AJjldx2xUcOFkX0hYtpAJ5CA933jg5z5GVms4ePhKGbBHeq1u/TRhKbaQVbPd24F8GIeypJYBo5Y0XU0gFLFNYnJ2GZxI@aSt56mR8sNg0dcAnTYgDJtpfe9mbLXSXR@MNXFNYZb3JSW42PydO0fxY99KGMplgbGywpjuatrmES4zP2ohOY5JiNNvKoFZLwI9@grw3HXpXCTwMuGsQ@Vciy5VzuJson5zU4SKrW4dvAQqM86pjOgvEQU4jXvLTu5o4wOe3FQ19vE3bD2PRjUOaUeBtyWRJc0IVG1hXP7TjrN2iSEltbmUBYlnUWBHTrCNF3DOHGUrwfU/oAdxO8Y1c8MakNLHp3FyjiGGf86oLi5CijPSK@hrz7pOZoOdZ/Zb5lBZNTywTgz7wo3Mzhb18LXvW@OMnCj6raapr4U0QiLMkL9LeFTsTPQL9e3Iw0hy/R3p@wXoU/o9gbw1e6UjM2wyeZO0fFOam8peJuI0bsyUn4raqmV3yMf9vF8iM0MXI4NHSsW66nsmrV6uUwPpEU12k6i8rncXNYldMFHPWOMr9eTmQmFlXLGeW7Jrx5ESTH9z0GmMe7cVaSEKP2cLj7/fEaqOZlJ@uT@YwN8qRbzdKr1KlK1d8t2E7KlLsMYuV2mr5lLBxHLCfG4FHVnHIaLGQxN9Ya8sJCaaIzH7hqcxNCp1gTOBsLsb3sT772xuEhsVBeMqNilEJgDqoIiuoT@zTbMIX5xTOZ3fTLXak@HZfVVMX3KhEa0mALz@H4/5GpnvBBw@C@fJtm9HbAVppgEHuYkiw4GaBrbcwoK3T5H5LSVqhhugqvpbMdZLlbXM/iUwxWUvCttmcON8Vkju9YT2Kl0iSvgVRdg/g7y8QxJI/BvnTdTmsCHLoUep41gos/tnCQiU/5wT5kGVyOD1JLuKcHFqbH4M3JxU5d/bA4h@Eqi6lmijCxA3f8/4pdOabwcsBSPtDpyzqbGfnHeNqQ3OiTGIl/ouSkLg9HmVHNGXBnp6m9SgX8fL@tKrcxM5I5epd4XQtQhQZ@DFdQGfyion/BYYyBzrA3N@hC0sawEoG7pmky71U9sfNzkQV9zjgOCsTmP9espsyw2k/R8W12jHS2NzbdSIM4xxgA@8WdBdR4HpzVJVPoq/05trJFQuFwjJC9UwpUwyRn1o2H5DArOQcKSHVeeQ1Q257kWoMPlaJ49HsbHsdLg/BvJoqsfsdmzNhezGS94iGjOnyHGmgEip/yxbF2XIYXylUjZcplcCh@zyWSx061YhmFVz@gldtYpQphG4wk418aUpMpMa@YYl5miSaS@nvYynLg1rxVKr/KyyJb52bVSpi4pmH2USuDuCwg7/yGR23eSuRQL0PUfGr4HAfv0k@w@R1yugVbUbCqSaHjFrXq3FKfrvZ8dZcYKmCJKerQ4bN2roucfYArTQaJxSz2Kr9kuW1OXRjKhZL@JurALfEM1BbnwxbSId4cIvAz7kMZRO/xMQK/NfLQkEBx8XlQ6TXbNLWeXI7AlS7GKDE1d8DUWceA2YCrJpuaoDxBSYt34SUF4kxjeN1iJVOuhyp7sa6Rl7kqhvcrdnv91Qy0ksVMqa9yHkHB9SOiZ5bfWeR6GaZSxssBHnpZ/3wdleelGDmbWMJR7ISfhiltc1hNhH4g1DZLh@AJmMZaRSo2wyMSkybr9G1JbXJXRCVjg6erAbcVYmWuPE5Lpr@NcAzI7Szj8DSWHPJcVp/FYLTHMZKOK@iNU3i7F9RGkGq1eYm4ex6JV9yXhrVQbESIdb4AFy3@lYN99dE1eXmMaGs@/WDDVco03qdV4V8@W/mAy1la5H2TVm2agzuGJt1olKsgmOs4sD/MuPYMXC/hTyN5CTu6@tHEN2OYx@HJpEvOkxjcR7TAipgyGExGOu8jXXIktjb8GEvDj87ISDWLRs7czCRl8FZ9IU78GVc3eAzF/chCKEvJhKqO/FQ2c8nm/gQwWXzLmRfnPHZCB/IosEfElabWm/yz8XVarlm@dLbjIiWI7HuNFW2V3IslgJ3dMhCcVnkJpNe2e8lPHsaoWvh@rMdhbfh8Q1Y9i8iLJbV6njg@MTKOc0XActYSsVDe1TRU2ZjT4iPWIaxNsxr4wQT0xEvfs/t/yVO/mDPoSmdKPigp3RkcqSeBlBjMGHTiJmZBrtvFUojT5A4cR/dFpTIQV9Ow24ZXVUjvaFMYK7Yiejq/eqYWDwYOeJ8W324ekPtZuSjnEL/Izag/NluiaO4v1ez5SorYY3C@yJqChl6Tu/GI2Em5SGdaDoOavfco5YWbAn5nTRkqx/tEkvznOPVnyAy7uE7I3o5jNYNjsdBgRPGgWq74NTuBb43DBdTSDvyrppMu85NLxKlSY05bZmlHMf1o9JvCavEovlaOcYifC@txl1@Ps8pxrGhSxJvfQwj9gylW7sfy8D2ygqPZx1FH6lCRqmmacVbcUYWXBjX1mkHyM6lV1ls1cWAJmxfTRFSlWj/ipe8olt5XiDnVV@7m8amaI9qWs4WU7ibxkmWeSuR6khzAqAihxx9iq7HfC9MgthbkpiuT6DZTJZ8W4amdDnoNVfPqH9iXD@QOO1aiyqKztW/z0Pf5c0yilpQeVqYp@NoNZ6xSj764bOTPPz5Md2cqeZn1c1q1M/RzcojBUFEzV1VaGk3D3BMD5AF4YyrkXLNIvjusFVcje3bG8Pk2NIm91tgscSSP8qM1pm6HWJrppTPcBac2Zsp9HDv1N6yOum0ZOxr2@ZVMcj1CLfNWP7jlcoKlwENRe67SSV9ZYX5sCcJKsFgXWY551fZDUsJ1MEnjJA6mjsWAWb/xCFz0EBvnav4JLwmU17dyOaQqjV78aqZ886O@7GRQ3Yz6qu0VNCPVa4nS3X/jBnn5OVPnGna18/JSVoqVPvycTvZTe@Ls8IRWM7jIMjdDlTpR2@GcjbiomSf1MAXyXqs4ZtrFOj6ZVsxC5qES9o4suQ7qYrUXxPs3cErdYWiEO49I3ZenlG5tTlRyO5HtmKfJb7A2wWd7ItmFw7YMdkylXQ9eK7NxE1mMGzkp8IM7UM@hv5CJP3Hk9mAlUdLJY7C0Mvk8xdQkBBMX6bq4gaC8htJoeFIr5ULXGIszsRWqZVSHWEPncCX39Wqpk4R5P59JVm2lKR6xWSxXS6T/UQLe3Q1j5HLjFNTejgcl9skolKUBsNb/r7sMos@hw7yKv9Idc2o3jj/MfcniVPvDzFGGuoVyCia576/Ep0jGm1c8VbTxQ1g/B/kRdsbnv6FqQumcScYGR5M8dVY1G6YJhxutWunHXjyu2wNCfafqxKqpqMBvfQJR5CQ9/uiuwqeAkHZNAvWpSwtjQq1@Xu4LabJbOmczsAwrrdkBbVlZmThp1KoZRWLsIDlRzksDxBGhgy2tnoHAgis/v1suxqhCi/E938AkdIvPnVF1odjNCaPLujjQryRPd@l4C5z5NdnYyqXEMNNF1zgNkpO8YfwthHVkurrljbft@C2P88m1RYy0y0nsBJEKTLG82FHb7ktVQcxhY3B2IkVVMWtZY74c6i@O4jWIzHRL077vD8HjrJjbIuS5SDPB@J5S8zHOwRry5gX@RKvdiWF98KSo@eNTcUSTuu@IJFs@8@VuhUJxXiHhY2mDmln1kncm5SZWLXTioprlXkQ7XO0sLzPkMQE7tYNqAshKW6w2MJfZ2Nb9ADHq0QYxS7hKsFaVrUtgGth8W8v9ZigYlIsJucnPx5cuNXGRmMj6bg@nw/GNYYkGOv9nhTxXyVkeNoZK8VCsthMFsY7HOuuxEWaQg4D4UGx3w60XV6QYi4rUGkYZaWUFqy1tBLirWm18/FiWVRoQXNs1gA8c2DE/@eOXgPUlguVbGRXVavyEvHSqzeaJ4/kauYkkM@yLW0@@szMovDgIwXVCHo7HCV1HU@nQYiM@jKn9JvuZ1eKSl9aZyHzKrQ9jQbVq@bqb3PBx9m3q9rvazR3S3iVXGQyBV7ksJ5P9bWPA3WaFqWljtT2QdaWVlDmPnw2wBsp5Ttdow3LiMr9kdPgpvfXaVRnpp@bQ8LVLjEty39mP22J5WBIbvX5Zj9uA0jF8HAwSj248oGkwFOutOIgsoQ0/8infCwba@cjXKXmJ9mnB78qJ3Jz50hg@aSrWH3saqE2e54ZyfEgWRyqj25kqt/P9SakwpahtQeeN2fTLBzz680o7HrvKGqOxFhGIw2E/EizeE9EjXX26KY7mKzFwSvdv6vHe0Enj2Ubp1e0W5j58w6YuuVdlYViLteH4vkQ0eBn2dprGTLyxEmSln4zffuTc06WqXnKMixmG5TDz5TZx5/QNiRd3/tg02WPVBx905M1n/K7KFE/2grgTCc4H/OnCu@QcWno/vaSF5c9f5uxtesKqTcdJuT5HzKVvm6bvOgrZwe8sN/TJ6Q1yN9MPd118Nnby/Bv8xTqruP9FrK0kskPs@5NozJRJ7M1us2/UDAfueZve@t2LvRy1wL4EZ72cF7KkLl@cDKXQcbLXP4LC@ZArcVZja55decexPjeGJqhtruPh6aVM2bcJ@KoONpjldSR9lMTECPENY2b6worWLM6o4vIpuWuvWJyRRwqob/iVgZ3JMTFXyenUPO7COOZfi8x6jbnzNMDaRMK0WCLV8YNcNd8UUkiDW9j75xE17HQi3UEfOdW@LPxZHJ5Xs7ZiqUwUdxyhf1jcpU4qyGkOcfwOvwh81lNG4ujlTY@syq2OlO/F12yYckbqOJAttZ/ndDqanv7Cxs5psHODnJTQBFft0URH0wLMWYzx47S4xOlZXI@lRqiaTwG8Lo7D/Dmr5sk3A9QSlHUW98F53Wm6pQV59oW1JDl@mgJmpQx7tbmGBbkaC@CnrGQrc0sX84fJ1pqUyLbkjIpcQx3D9bPayrdcPMyu7@I8I9pPPNW0rQ3OyfZRdvOMvnw/iY0gAmMFRzpYqiqaaxiFP/inHauFIw2p4kzH@mJRAo6TS@beFp@vSKqvubDNkjs/hmlx24K9aLnrE3ezHg85nbhqzSrIw0ojvtaIvSu/1EcYlgcV6ojHcz9tf1Jfh/vY3nCm4GccBJHLPlTBms46yFrJHv0byxNLYnCGIn2KmdXkYJIxs0WyWALVygKM0T66khxV/HQR@q6@t1rwczgd8UxXnNO/5iQ5UVX/bzhIPsHwLPbDWOeTyB4/ZiYwK6WpowSrJRzPaRVt8yC3Nbx4Wzy5I4F@VHC4LatWu7FKSuAdpLv3xdpF/GyWkv5/BPvUEZAbVa1EwVP6W6XwUe1SWGTvbpiMXtW8h5xN0plPVTDRu0cURy6OhpwW04FvOoa0Iz2qTBOTJ@Yy8cZ2Mxtu1Mtjvn8br/0sV8FF/mrrKTyNCfpIfBttHJjpaNBMFWmrSsStZR7MhHkUm4sq5vfY3UOxafM1gXiZV9wtTzXswGN6dviyDsb2wj6a5W8@H8kh2XUsXa6WKRvEjZ9FOCqPlQu1o2y3fCC1G6v@8jxTliKOPjW3VUhWCRXPNLv/Ssb5qU7@xNAY1615LDs2BplFzGLLrc0LEFdwBB7ziyKxOw63WrS7wr8lnKsVCBtT9JXcpLcMGJLUrnN59E3Ev@VYNTWXJS8xAelYS5mCS31pY1RtiLVfryZrxJ1BG9hJpK48PEXpZ/jlGsf7MKg2twaEL2CnazET7zvF24TXqYh8nMdTSSS3MY2c4MtokzzIc2Db2wYatWnkFo5QbCUYYquG5CpPp@bycbY0Id5hfJ/F1@LsKUb3zqJ44hPxIRMXzbzPJHfxbGCtELsLOhrXqCG/sWuneAzx6WSHnHBU59eJkwW8nzpmpA4DpOdHJBIiRrGnVMhjCtHEnPOCC/8@mHqIZmdmRVcvYeXBpa94xpXUxXkw9iZTCsQcDNMCfgXE4o4@uk/GCoXg2CIfP0GefolPDhwKJ/N9qevWV4zw6Qcsh6lZOivbs7DT1su@/hgOhjGunoxy34y/qcWxvm3wZtJXL8wr/4aw2ZjGRLETgD89vJal4Y3cRKmqCu9ashZ75DkkRO2q7iOqHkrkNLCYssub1BtOdIi5Pkpu68jKZ3WqruvKhLWUo34YYrqlWlXnWpSYvmaFYR2bx73cNOKwd0LME@PMZmq9uSdNzc9dk5xYdjBps7D65h9aEu/P0NoRc0rSfBMrzrlRHd2uVCKlNZPGu9x6ceXiKEVReXXhhFzSUqydX@NzsVLKCFjFeUIcXOGVrAGx25nrV1sPh1p2tIO4vyBozXguKMLX9upYCs3vce3L3QzbFbzL0OI0l9XPxSzrRjFV1qb44mCoMkFehmix1frBsvEpedB0E51ncY2McFUV/6nLI6ovcJSMrWyS4iFeZmCsxEc5GaBx/8A1TBZdk9clOYsQ5yhu/ZkRvhUvhkynGwLwSPyYomo7SxeasZlHRJwscmDMpkSuKVltF@9Rs6D9agtecS5OcmZSmIBNOMmGq3sQrmlsD6diVdc6Das8pnFAakXkRm6T1dkZ@lmeR4dws5SSk9XRFgz3dBS8hioNfiWyhIrOZOSZ2yryxifUBn9dpx5fKvtwUiTeXO0EE6KlB481UyQLL4n1rm4geVpNa@/X4r4MRyQy00QXVGX3KO5hfDCEYqcvQ9xV2DbkBI2KTZ3b2ySC7umKhrdtkOe08x5@JPaordmExiNtuU9UmeLV8lAD/gblwNlcx245g6dq1Z4j3PuwHlPcaSftPFYUxnQtyEMQvtczajdjBnHeG5wvVp0fg9FswGWPXMxF0Ym3iRMl6QyOpTwOeCSRkt2t9lKe9OHOQEq6xx6zAH/6gIRuK4zpptk/tQdWsTh0aEm5RnloZsybtSymLnR4qpWLGjzMM5n@Zn5xMwmMTEZFqe1zxaMp@KnNwPeeSrlKgTeCOH1ZVucI4@mr6dS2ZbxG9MA6M9oRA1ebPGV3y2OJeLpyGobnsWvASSuLSBcdfoHzGWavYBrcljWaElOSiV@FchNGs13hT7vYGivEVtmDnUJcVelbiHp17PATWbM0gjy3kjyZNIDtQaz38@Nb/F1soC7azqeUfGR3CLU0JpX3cJUOMP8d4XgWn7TMTa/dOXLSgI/D8hLCIZ@Tg0zyMrI8qafPvsEYXkyfqU8PKYbxuyLav4DxfEL738Ne28eK7aLfR0671U5P3GnUBku1uybNjzd86n5bX/6iY2Ru1zDOTiKKSRK4mepRsx1f2fKnEahdeN/leozamryu1svX4I2NoFEO5CqtABd@htSpqNBGcXfo/QqaesQ0NcxnHSRCbYN/bIlivPzStOAgMDHSV0u68qgduGQVOzancBTGTHwcQ5VjLBvIK4EtpVs7INbabJwYcB0zppaB/CiNdvDRl6RtJUE6dBmdahfEFmF50o7zLnahlsLWxfSB0xrac4OMdQ17CbYDdfKSEOSnpn7GCtUWPxNlHhwt1Hrz1WpuCIfqgIO5c6E7Xp5jSsVDQHDAZ6HFbMfN8N7jc86xGokTfXFuOcf8kp02A3czueFjGfXeWDBFWifsVWoDJMPt99LbWeJzOS3tHMRej28MKcittrBYcJOzLLZe/C1PwMXyvEoccLfC0UXQmn1o2hNfMcfRNsbm7CBVEkdN88OLBNjT@2mzT4zWI3GEaojyuww@xYn1FNiHmYOyZmjsbTltVjNJvB97nYX8@ylwwp/mfi8XyVQzo/CO4EVbWcJ2lFBYS2BY/cF5Xjgsw3lylR/Th4u3SR23XNbOhOOrr5y2jecblrEX4VcSQ7gxERQSq2o23qIPwwpRtRL6dtBpO7KfOep3JFllpwK/ZulQEx6qcJKIvULY0mAmVRTD2BvPbw6aaYzfb1vl7@ZrdQGUeZuMqsLSkoIaXBcP4bIVDwXsok1F/g8W5c3E4xN5R65S1VaufrL/PSlehdixln50q20kEwV9w7iMUsX82Qyu04mD67JCuexIS@XXm3I@m@ITvhTeEK32r4caQuLwMyV4Ylk56EmdH3IMjChV9JxDRfKQEbnMwr0Gn2f16d3tLIYv5KEruU8dQnuW2yVybRkdeEVX34QRzE/NmgRy6O8iFVKt2A0JwZ/w3hDWgm6sVYppOI3q4JGccD88ysx0qeYpQ1oqGRu32GDR@rtanX@BOZDwVKdj7rCdWUFqf1A7HR2avNER/I5p6pDbSHVk2FzN6F9twHoEMXejMHffmwl3Bz3rFdMsdqLEURED94CaL5RrrZrDV4cIfo/7FVEfuPJiEnBTX6XOaUVN56otGH7syXE8zOEUpp7ZfFFQ/tM5g6cucca8Lda6cKLOom8l0m@fp@U5taNTXqbbQnExHooXTVWRuAcCyTs7ONSquT7/jhQmD3d/0ZyaXsjoU@zVmjWL7@qgwbc2vNbJWSfllTFGbcyRU6a0Z1EbEC3qzKWcJWnbS/2Xm9UG51zs1r@5hRWnBScLOuYmW3QhH3YMUxU2g0JKRtS5rM@M5wf/kUL8a1dHktTRR/zM5a/nYsxiDrbW1PbmLcpFhli68Lc@lw/bxp9meRxiiGEzcDxbHafg4x9rmdWeoyPfVl1/vO3Te12Wq@kMQ8hUdEnW4gSshkxFTeLKx94808NjKEFjzszG2bIv7gLkZRwfu2nT5zZad3UoB3csusMYk@yX3C3J5VCr2oPShcMJOa1nzL9m53bir3/drAqeC2x00e/rVb100Tu5ap6Kw7s5rKeqvdEhwcHTNRltjCPGcGUKycPFhPEk9sgFvO/FF6V3/80yYW1kyGNQiW9CcDLOBvnhh9l5vER2433C6Aws5VgriUxqYzZ4YvrwqgPM1CaWtCbqKbW85aXwXZVLEjFcoWIuVEep1IFaseSXYFdXSpBe8ZJP0YnL8tq9MIOHOkbk39x6vKslJjfVkYJFsY81@OeHiVu9heHXxGCpWIvZWcY7K83qBnny1fHPQ9r4pBOPoXldcUNwNbMn1PN/xB6o6UzSLVFjP@Egrwo2HRs@IvT3B8gKejkbxUMpLsQxSp6g5DkPJ0BP@yrw1MdBkD7wvLAQgZWBdDrwY706MHrlW6gOFVt8kiIZm9f4UkqUbOBnw5jfkjoxJRdpC@z7aVFxLCjyPRzvEw4D@dWhWjLeppdNNKVnnonhIEvHAjM2MrumkR1Rp3pDwtkLymmqyju5o322yFvv1HKTmtUiI7rUvuVeXmRv8JfrSGww7c7SqiwmHufxZ2kyDDeGVPxiYMQwkn6WqhMIz1MEVxzsc60khMe2HI7Ngm/BobHkjl@zCTCmRauD7wRjE015EF48FBWahP30GRLjWSQDaJ@SV20sPVFbCrPwOUslpMoFjZwlpoyE6zmQUPwbmYmob1X7hhRBkNOfdW3ymjaP1@p28USoqfN932ZKfcqVidbZArkeeNt6d56WIK@tyvzs3Ca560ovL2VizUsXY70hSs5SE3Ezm5iBv1PaGPpk1VcVEPz/Tm2uOx@g@y7EvDCEi/yaqGC8C1aKUy0qqSO6dnhqR@QxTB16zZaTDn7uLR1tFy@ZlQlGy8z8@W3SyZ055Dsn1oJOdYL5U7@cLqTn4Iqx2TqvFjDu8XUJR/4pVTPy2omvkc1yMwhH33xyhV5uUv3UHkvWPISoe8oAS65acGZM/JWX@K6CZfb1YYKXRwdVhg3Lpb96l8c/juStHtTTB3cdqqD7Fp8p5ticObayh6fIFBzGVlFBsNKLEZsmbaiIhPSFA7mUJ6qgaQLpFpsDqVhbSGrnF6dUwU9MiB7GNAsUu2GwrE2sMxnZoYFUM676Qb04qgdwPCTP6nyS2tX/nvL8Rk6Ti5nI2JeLuvCc4AES5IPa9sOIto7BPB0S170cRXX@gq1AfmqTGy2ODXJblTOkdh1Mc@zOXjGXx1YPwZPNPHkamJ/FXqidbqf4OsGLbuQqoxLvlgur1BQFPpbiSW3mu41ZUIcyr2uokhlEZ4vqbIKc1eTV4CoHG7nkFRc@J6RTunzvI/KMi8mqeNh82w75JGf5jQtNKkwYOhRhm2optyqtcIjq5YzhehIf1ZnVVhDOkPlbKGoP/mNupTxmaOXEn4G4xs9dcfgVlc1efkoIg7VMHtp08jCjpmd74J0fxGpNXiAswerUhV2drItkjUf4fpgrGemZxmF4byl@9ASrnapi8w9iNmRi2iSDmGCuHBOT35hYUvKCDaXh6WqdluS2jYuebHzKhimwtz08UM6icOqHP/Ek9TUYZ6PV5hna3bg84Zf8dgDOXE/VcjEdFSR2AuswKG8Kq0Hh1MBOdX6WQfZlkoTvpdS@bYIjhJnH2UNP7akXuMwOL@jUJmI1uTqI007WITe87z4hkL1ZUXvgyusyB9XZEhu@1WW8Zehb0mwLjeeqhS2GNcZkwVKTmusaGGIquiGyS8d7R7Ezi1e1EOZ4O1bKbK62Gaj1hPNk3vupnky1YqDBN2BfFpeuujmSJnnCdZTaCKkXdxNMC6M4JinO9tbOlaqDz0NKczEU3Hm52GxtwPGMWtRRS9bredlYjcE2Waa0FpttCYQtM9eA2uwUS2Q/Umh84d0OGmG7KUwR8kEh7tqxVaQU4BobfV@SlbQMY2aVGCdEQW2HiuJTEWXwA9y@Nar8TIG5Czv9szHDavg/U/mI9cZ43E0Vp1KlncpL2/wMbgNS1EnYs3G1g19NPu3Uy0NjYUo03uVhI/nND9@aGknazkjC4DNZVs3D3vODe3K4KTlcLePhTitnOrW0UTPTga8d7M8WjkLwmqlMooxwIg5Wy2GUc2rHPPHrB8cYf/st1sn5WHxbWu6nQW/p3Ht8Sy6LyxNb3hg9cT7uW5o01aLr0odVYm86isylTgV48OJbvDhLD5zzSXdJJEjzUFtCXXSnuCP7a/xx25ml3uCgVmdc@K2bkLMYAuQ97ptop2ts6Rlj/wbeDs5/ns2aZDIfrahjajPKSak6ZRSh3lnUgPs5mNP4FEa4MjoOq/BrWl7o4Ie8GArv5Jblugl1um1LMbN6a4cvOdDydvxCTqca8XWEEXLN/64IRksq7gLxb4kijzBjd8Q8jccc9mEvWx7CaVOHtrCDQL8aFjXGzxr1OpRhunTHd17Nr6oXHNjV4qU6/KoOTfmEMP26a@WslQH0PJaFm9yQ3l4dDsNYlamXApkS5tQbUIzjveoUSoTa1DwxUshk5phXh7I75K6tBhd9NNRRIG25CWPRgBiT8XcpqJACTa1rvtXgFzTBY@@ccuoqqWYjJSOMX6utUcFVQyVyNakm3slgV5r0ST7aVaUWm4QJayVclZ5vb6U5pX2YVSoiSaQPpLY9tvzQRDRdZFIFapYGsFmTq3a9FlEhnLfgbJIR8FOd86sT@7zchmKNUXneVz@AywF1DJLPgXpLwunAKO7ru@dxPD4WldDCUTzDEVXKOLqhTW0E1TmRfetP756P4mfiFL5l4bCrPgA785m0xU0wNWrD27EMY3wpY//RIBdzau@QnEX0jAzlw9iBkxz860vGeaxacq4LZrPPKQz@f/54XqRxVllPPynVNhHPdFeqJvFpkSrWtjNLjPsLnBqwNo2bCZj1o7Anw1qiwWZ7fzzLUTuJpmpY7eP9rMXu6DyD/1S8U5nJcpOUQRecaMmitnyYRvqJwgv1vgajKk7sav@rNQTXBpYdRfBUilp7/V46ILeTIQFqu0hfKlxU8ROjzDWv2G6fLc/VRb29pedisWqAEq@zmx1dhTc3MGm6nKTgxX7CJH7OhkzAlDUoLlIsu2WekOcEuZ/3GRZrhXrL0PTg2zSJRcy1LQZ/rGbyT0t0ZRfOYkdC6ctRHBSLKZuZflNxLP91cVD2Bm0DnXIXN4D7gdwOXDSGqtWaJkLzFBu92M4fw0lYTr3cVYk6j@c0EAhGvC6VE@0PQ9hvw9NiBAu@TnwuoF2e4UqgHsDR3GB8/qCahUrty83VlmJrtIcCTANnFjZZWhFrh2KcGq1uW1Bze1/Zhz31boY/OChQInxbnWPt7dONv@1pMomrsi1JKZIfxJ9NE6jKqFVN3zKZw60OjGO7N6dl1h@U7Z@pCNZgLlHvZfmEm1Ec8Vmu5Vk4Jsvluk8cBrWI@r9Zxc@xcl0PU1cCfXSzrN49M9@kTr9omcGefAsYDB/EpXTwM54Si9oap9j6TcuQKpF@4nI4pUTOouW0spIF3@3I8Ntb06yE3Ec1@aemkn9Oh7zt/PxJ4BrFltw5M5OGB59cTX9XO857i@FpHcd9QYuczauTuyXVk/7Dy/SS3KlZi5suuRuIEtcC/pbie2cEHMsBah@BerXZa8XYkDhKesrxJy23n3ZmLXg2M5QkaqPbjnjYhqcd75Nj89VsSL2vWLoDKb3oVjv@jk4RYc9qU1RArQ/D8HeIXGaOU/CckOOs/UxFZ7k0mlMdxzwdHSWpinqFxpfqCZZdT4SkuZU3b8NUmCS3xbXYjTeEp9CgHpwUVNUQ1RsZDY3i7mTydtZQQhzCXbsk9hkWNHTlU26u4gyy8191aCYoGKai2aDagDT86sGun9jblvgNZWsFPfk7I6ePXHfdFYcfy@rlJavZcl@F7znldWqSmvrinmOyBk1Ovb2WyTsppz1ludiZEFP5ImxJiZQ0BYmVpN0zP7WJdAz2JJxMRmZomLWP8T1OLAbxtFXo5HW6L3GIDzgmexnlNqSFKFwdSqMzz4om5FpP7vidlKVO9r491lYpLwMLYp6Sy3H1jh6TPGRiI9C3TdzLdRqVtrL11bzOKk6futy6gK5sHJYGqoWvspwxOe3D34YUcWrkOkYtl7jKxxPxY4pXq/eXfQdLlavgOH2InOjoqu2SCEKXkFsXe1I3ueFGrNWNObVsfo3U96VAT6Z7bUxbxOcixsKjPNcx@tT0rXonXt0yPzOVz8w1kJsdcplGljgtGaAPvr29DfCqEO4i7HTW1qp9NPk4z1JZZ4xlk0VbKRfqRV5Hao8aY8HLVHc3gnvxjqmXChDkbyrmNVo1yedZ1IKc2vX8V70zJqCwiCb/OTatXmmCtRgx1oF1p3rHhrevRiy9AxGl4ViPVS@2gS1IQ4H7IucNFJ/RLGN6Y32X5alXHYlLU4d2j@OwH8Rocg7FsbI8l@sZMYbIU8hbQnoVdw2OsnGl75oiX@ynN/TgLA5ferGRif1FRvZD@3JfPePYos4cwDQfJxe@uC5X81arA37d/mzTVkqy/hORpOYk1F6Ap15Yc/uCsD8XhO0JmoEJSR0wJt/Py6OfGCvwPsEfNqofReCOaHj81JsV1fsyIrBVXaaPVjuZxZjKamYxCgfJHKdV7ZomS9@pPQvFenweFLWMmigvefjcn52eFVxShKdGMSUbGrA/IuYcuugY77uxwbwcrOI7ZZIs8FoyqV4q81g@KnbthHj8F@SmOZm8dUrb3Mt1xdumUG8Nu32SyizOAvZOnmdYkln6sU5WNWbBUs2K7uVtL9eu2vTVxvTlYYF3GYyT5vagbIb4Zxi7/ZLqqJ1i4xOVFmEHfuvlYRLblR2zbRmLST3YmlJ7sBvUQdj8OTmniuny5@i2GhZxVQJ3Ff4F5rHHa@pc2C3ZejeTKuaTljcdhBenMZvG4H1a7kgRqfxXfzqBHLpYI08pWO2eyVYb0/R@6jTrSa2veGfkYXlRrRfRDepQ61eYYiLn8aO4D1/U0YcV/ItUB/ljpsUyxu9vtF0EKivMDXFO4HBmDlZVyNz3FZD2nH7dwV1yHsv4u1M7w/3EkT9ci@@pJZVvs0ivteKM9s1pww@fDLGUq1pyTq5zc7Cvg1ED2wS@jcpDf2tTttjrYI6cYFw@peN7FyugawLhnTqUMEaj3YZTYu8UTWnkNU/cg7E4qsJquVyWprHkrBgqZWTdYKVSbiLj5M6fpX16CMPtPCJwjrGu3sBnq4a3UTOUmySnpUk4TavyV2sdb284cfbVkjPO/FpCKxoXcFZTPk5d8RIWTku/W1C7AmubK9TWdrxraU1Ub5iESZ8h9nZchBNYHyvUvq738qgqZQvu/NXhd3cyC69Uee0fpBftE0q5uueL68OaVRHcwhSux0WrDifqkNCb/r7nwz6VqsnykrnKKPxLaU/wSUwl16ld5ye05W5mnXpR3CpuqXljh0Ya@tTBJTxMz8Koo53UYdYXg9i7m@h1bLTXqPmo@IFllaIV/5VlqmPO8dgqpA5tUq@CetWnjNCRR1UzA6ReY2JbbC/@ThrkbBb7S11F1Jc7yTns3VbLHE6binGfksGcf6fW8IqjS5dwy7KwOYOXfWGx5KUtz1m5JOFdNaHl0BXje0@XyvVdDIx3g0mMaTJHmXpfTYi4ZjngfwSmWy7ktmJY7kPUuwe6W9Q2PahNiw545@bEVAZP5ywrsSOqLHwvEU@oPHRmw1uF9V616PmK43YcxpH@NhM7KF6dg2Jbnq2GkyaclPOg9p72fm3b5FJ9Qmw/zNnk8hO8FvolFmNvNLY3LaDjzWdPYo8Ra2U8zsMMajt1ADnqSRuv3j/ngnemFut9TXKpDj/pBnGdEoe72Tl5zsxj8viDrThxzOXPVnCALEOGYSwtIe2slP5fc@/@ZXtWlvf@nr8C6ZbuFrq52iIXUWjAaxA8gxAdosVmsylodrfVBWFpcBgkiWR4OeacGKIhYyDYKnhQGw9EhThGrT8sZ629d9Wa7/N8nnfOVbsazy99qaq11nd9v3O@8708l4uvvnsX0vdA2pd2X3aXN/zOU9vf/o3t77xi@9IHnr14aT/b@fuL735u@zfvu/irx9//yj1A66vbL773535gP@C6R9v/872k1sVXbu/@49vbL76we6y/t6uOvvvO7X/aJSGv3X75yT095//ZVal7SsnzH3zrrh7aLZBXvbD9k3f9@i9tf//2vQ7mF39j@8UPveGJXRn40sXf7cPPd3/gF3ahdvsXn/vg7ll8dZe/vrTXZNv@w@0fvPjuR3bn0q42uvjWK5/bg@y3L/3YGy@@9aY9KO2rF1872efNX9r@4/PbL31wly393v65fPPjuzX4h5967idfuXtmX3vmkfNd7PzKr31inxi8cd/1/pFdAvHOV@6@/@/88C@@Ya@p83ef3GOhX/XxZz9wsTsx/8szP/D8xdc@@4s//N6Lb/3SL@/lEz//03tk/N19JfmFp9@1/a2TH7vz6e2Xf/0zP7G71N9/9Xu3//iO1350@ycf22NQPrXLlf9gl6a9@PzupPyr7d@/dfc8fnC3Nbf/8WNPXPzTv3r1ez65ZxH@zn749oYP706o990Tg/jdT7xhd43ffOOTe3jkPRT4S9vvvGr7f/3mXhjm4n89vYuyX9w9t//zdduXHt0dz9/Z/s2zuxj07d3t@KOnt3/x2ru76L@rgX/y6Y89@eYPPvUzuzz@2x/c/t@PXLz0yYu//PHbH9h@e/dcXv@57T@98Sd3Ve3n3rL9wvNP/B8f3n7nx3/6fe/Z5UEvfOK59@xOs@/ttu6f7Gv3v7777Csuvvmqk0/d@ejujv7WXv/1Cx949@5AfHEvoPGaf/nkXvD4H/Z75Uff@YFf@OSbti/@@vYPT969/R@/vCs9f/cH983nfS29u8o/3E@9tv/tE/tZ6S5c/@WHzj/@gff@2@1XH/nBd//LXeR88TOv2gMZfns/lHjs4jvv/8gbL777/O4e/8n260/t1X3@8eJ/PrHXzHr@7Of30hdfe2aXXL314m9@9OLF2x/e/sNbn9z@u9ds//Yzb3tkPxx/dN@WuPint@zS8Ee3X3jv7oO/87aLb/7S9vPv2q31L7xmj1d7zzM/fWuX0O@qo7du/@dT97b@d3/@X71@Fxb2reOLrzyzpwP8@0e3f3Pxp@/c/var95JVf/7uH3rmRy/@7PlPn@8W@zcvvvOBV7/jN191@6Pbfa7w9XtaXH@w/c@7Yvi3Lr71kWd2D@i7z1z82W985FXv237r4tsfeup8z9LZY6Z2W@Ybe4Txnuzy5O7GfWcXOv7f7d8/vluM@9XyD3e23/rpn9v@/qc@/pbt1/aKb9/7zGt/4R0f3u55cH@wV8l4fK@Z@vybfvatF9959Mf3QJdX7wcM39iDY7Z//Mz7P7lbaP9@t1L@9g2fe99u6f35/gb@0Kd2G3T/SL/6M/t27vY/3d7@h10Q/tL2r5/5@V/c3anvvfLDu2f@0sd@5c4Tm0d21/FH73/Fr@yOut277PtV39h@8bOPfWr7tad3H/Pli7/6yC70vPjcfhi813ja/vUjT97aF@O7guqRT@1xST@1/e@PbH//Y7vs4MWLr7ztPRd/uquF/@vr9zz7j@y@6x7@9N3NxTceuXXx4tMf2n7hZ9/yoe2X3vz@53Yn9Z5I/fXXbj//A0@@afvld75r@3uvev8jv7n52d3x9L3ddfyv/fDwJ7Z/9FNv3379Qx/Z3b4vv3Dxtx/517vn9tVfeWIXRf7sDb/@ru33Nm96xdNP777snz6yOzX/469tf/f9P/vx7d/93PZ//Jvd5X7@p35x@5efufjrR/eoxM@@cRfJX3zd9isf@5Gntt94dHcb92oXz@2@7V/@xsXX3rX7fp/f3fNdvrtXO/z2XnD3j3fp357Y8J/3OkVf3ycPdx792Pa//MLuq399z5DfK4L8m@0f/tjPb//41sWfPXHxtz/82XuyWPvh8pfuPfX/cPEXv/zo7vVfvhfR/@5X7yuwn779x37p9O2nT936@MnZu5776O2fOH/8idecPvn207e9/g0/8o43vuktT7/5NSdvP/mh17/5zXdf/c7TOz919/zx07e97h1PP/3qN/3Q6VtOn/jlJ5546hPPnd791c2zv/rqx07v3n7sf7/1Xzz36fPdSn3F21/xscef@Be3nru7l3h/6tnn7jx@/xdPvfDs6a3bj7/uNa9/3eueaP7gSf/92e1f@/Tp2e3HH7t1T@f9sSeeunV2@@T89k@evPDxxx/71Ed/ePeTTz//0d1PHrzVE0999PTO7RfOH3/s47c/@9gTT/zvBzrzm2fvC80f/n2pOL95di85v3l2rzl/@O1efP7yN/6K@3@716Yff/rC7bPNs585eXb8x/g3@39vbj34u8s3rR8xfuzli@7/3329@82zD/TzH7zL/TccX3X/0u599v3/vHybez@6/9EPNPPrC@8J6O/@dU9B//KdD1/u3svrh19edPmf@7@//Oj9e9x75eGN6nuMV3DvB/XzLy/q3u@f3bxw@f6Xn3b1Zvc/8P7f3fvAq@vZv@jBN7x0BCg378FH3DMJePCL@285vPLqYR3eYXiUeqvqa@BpXz6SB59z75/3V8vhIy//pr7y/td88GUPFzPeRbndD74erlXbG/de@@AVh78tX7Wsh/Dm4@/Kw7j/TvrQhu9xWLyH@1G24v2nhGu13rerD5HvPDzgy5f7pvN1Ot6NcS9fvseDZemL6N4/r96LdvaDF9Xdevm@wwK7CmDDh9y/04cbGJfr4a9hY11nqeryONyW@u8hEo27eP@PskVtRw/xCq4oPaHLKKJr@Oo97v9CVsd4VfarGn9LyHzwkEoAvff58sDL/rp836vdV0MrLerLb17jzOG/xu10eaHlrpa4Ibdg/N39DXf4z/Fm3o/X9ZQcXkrfe3ji@vDKn3nEKXt2@ID7/3n4mPuvvPzO/NdjOLr8y/FneP53b3LYTMMfjN9Yb7Efl/w9hj1t93zcgVdL5zIAj89aD6Ly4fffXNKazS1MFsan@@DuXGUO9z4xBcUHEWr4rEPoLXu1xhj9VnoE1hRDf1q@JgSJy3O@/MVwKQ9@ffUNJc6XLAETm/qOdvZR4ua7u6yiw607LLYxVRoe74NzsbzfeI/jcx@2aHn48oAl1F2eeocYMXwyfNbhSPc/fPBeh6c/biHPSMqGrDfVEiA8ASQQybpI/x7e21JxLQz0I8LKGDcv74iyr1NyKxVHWUHjc4In7Zc4pL5j7C8faCnW1X/YTk1R4vInVw@9xOXLl1/@0F@nu7pcl27xehJqqjycdoebSOvKDrPJrUwpR4mAdi/LrZP7J/8rqbV@/v2LvHrjq1uN94oOksPt0HtUkzQpYeVvw12qifMQ386G8ko2vpQPuNrsJeVuwQrKN/De@@FRu7xb4fiXFAnu4HUX2tU744EXDlUJu/jXfEMh/IXdu7k1LojLJz9UI4fFvnh2LZwnmgZNDxT84f3ru8qppZszVBzlBKZMlrOYq8cxJhYP/qcuNYoiFpiGW1K/x5jeDafeeF6VuFRrCYwEwz0fyobxNsMKGXPt8oG6ag6LedxVpbI9h9i4uQWHSr1pUs/XD2o/jcOOPKEhoNVio5zF5fbLRj08jfoUqCd5CJy1eD1kjcMT0yuuO/RqCY57j6q6oR8kZ0y9Nn32ZT3bKi55/PBzeT0flIevOyzNWtHpQsXVB0GCdpOcdaXleZUKWlO2tA5KflbfT386hgMsn6QYGb@rJ/bDn9eHW@sCXeUUN2XlU/N6aILX1SZvpTFMl2rdHONjGkPYUBlYYjX8jtoXddEebs@DA2roCB@aauXNKOJpc@ywTPkUeOBR23f7S78QmjLl/Q/1bG2dap@xbH7skB32pbWqJg3UPNyQVrx2j8aAehXUNfWvK8j3WNNRhXV7ea1XT0ILyzIC8G3ocbnEtau3vdzTmglKLoW1Au0zTOqbyrG8jm5A6pOU44vHDjWTL@nevX/Y2EED3tA/T5ehGUVtYo17zrtzD7bLg200fAc@W3QoIQeS9cQPF7C5ZUPB@uz2f3C1JKxUObyJjUiGC6uV8/0vJX268eS4Cv7j2eUPfQg0tfV1CNEl7T1coBSp9S0t0OktrAHPVko@QmuDqn7a5V3BEUM56@Vr1CNLt1fTjxvrMDst69Ffsy7s8urJz5XZ4c/HWRQ9CSzXPH6G/iZ0ivn@jLvNB9Xjeq25mNyREtma32lI0NHbUL9LZT/U2xKJtLcmvcKhz63HDNy34cs3lQlFdywxauES5p66i71nhxUPr9x2VQNuILZSvFpvZnnQDJDf69Kq9Zp@c83iwg2iPO7qGwxxlELT5eOtYe7q1SmZGxPVWuw8OJs1mStrdmil4FfmYKaDDevMUpJnVX0GbYzzdhw8KlaG5@CpBVgje8oBD8iSE7gxdsZKNlBzwbFjNV5DWZgp6bi8cYfJS83dH7yX3CLelcPtG/MtnCmOiJux56DDJZs66rvVNVy@5j/rH9SV57AUOJ1kZcn5KhiA8R3HzTfCrfRwG5aYPquymfZ/cIgUEHYMvnT115CI1@Anc41a99y7qKu7WTceAuEQOHYZVxJyDCpCg63UZEh7gWk4Uxuk5eM92Rn2gR@C1kkAHAAUkFc36xCYQ4NaYuXJuE7L/HfYgbXYPmxVOaIQXAKHZZ2mnUJL7LAUUmE3hD1shjQx1hCQuEtrzut9OBlea13EPzjXJz3UR/hdyvNuV0tF25TDvB7gAXdUV@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@lsRVrkgVxgPCmhNRoATkDzg3h00jXNeCmW8vzEw1LMCDT@jovRFkpdICWRAXibQgu8bVs2kFM8uuEyAB1sxNAxDDPslUAadZDpuF@dGtXQ7dn/oZwW9renzBbBavCgXeH9ZQlnQ5PAMXpQ9xyWW70H/ezDrgmmCmN6YegAfn5yJpUjTsAgEjh0PRnOBlddafTa/NwWXcvRHwehiSNZdtLhcRlwxFkFfjCPFErbaxqGV7r0NudjaJNcdk0Uy0YXCPO8YeGjcYa018@k9abJDrTYcE6BGgOwVk@o0KvJGOz@2gseMw0@BnWx4MBX56calX331xS8/p9jUTdaGTJ34IADDdU9HhwJRgijkuHblMxJgbbjSnxwiVcLLwhMlP3DkxCF2R@6AONjnDDtsVi1VVCPUV1zV4GNwzUvODr5SYQCag76aIhp6frrW278AB3aKQDf9NMT3x373zA4XiojRhJWGr4erjqNzXHLDPeqjsnidz9RFCeCYSpKuXxYaWMSmgS2/jDgqeTNssMgpW4gqga2BY5MydmGelqztYQLgMBW21g4GodVuxjDzuPiQgQDdyZtzK9HlBxohyUW8X/D6@A49@JgJHuOkQCQGnB0aihr8HF6oYdTC05pbGCOqRLAJCsAY3OLf6QA5/I3pWWuCwCWGay3kVKYG0iQuJLkzbBZ4hkpoDcd6Ja3GhrzkpbR4EC4aNNzsZyiV9dh2VSFwaaex7DvJfvHZEJ0uKAimSPpvdtAMzTOjC1YRdBRDUhWHKGMEJz3oZkALQ18x5GWuXwwlgVmKL0TZbEJ6WGCUgLin307xRwH1k/dpMR1scTF4WTphKxQ4pNSBYBqCzaJwwK0NTM8hk1XLtWSknAGeMRJe8MRG@V7aRE@hjiskHBog53fBXId8RO9bA/A6rGrJ4Hv@MU4TKmVUV2wr4Q@B/0RyJ5LjdOMCYzmE7vGtbmEpN3JUhzfB7QEGxXIjCsvJ3DQoeFDfjxhIMM4159CKjRMGsehMqJGF8KiDOf1KiAprAndSknXjV18bhxGaVSsMrZmfGR4nCPssK4EwrjTkUxVqqOOkUOYpPVWDmPEeY4DUiy5IO0LrVFuwHHDaWXYUetUIO/KuqnojJLdrYy97MopzjMROtDtZLPbOqvxoZSsBjHSxYXk104YQbrNR6SKbXj0uGw4eGDNF5k5PUUJAKR4MYtxXbgA/QB5YtrgAerKeBeknPNcApjqGfAmJzcu1UyiHqOTpGRaNQpdxTLJBiQL0kV1kYyXkUYWVtsFHIPqAslH2cGkzU1kpjiCllQIjfnmJWESaDZVyXicCW9n/I5F7bNu7nYy4g0bTIIF9bWJCnhRFyTCPEHuNvGZeJ0P0MwxxYRe11jx@nVCCmUN3R76F1RcUnF8fYlgHlKthV/umpZjH2TAD1FZML04TcH96xACGRIrUqTHWJ/eXamBmWREWYPolQY4SQLZlWFC@TbwMssqpdHfkQGYGGrBvNznFC6q5gUQCr2DwCtvnNohoI@ZYUM1riuRSeJCxq4JHNRTnkZorgni5NqhhDKAW4Kh2TNi@wCJNAYlKjbt4VgvXajYkt1CnQytWXtiMNfoo1A4369ivgDX7LHTqcsy4STUUybmcROlqRRNggxVz0qjJhZ0yCkgFJa7eSjU7q@Bq@81HuYZ3gZwrmHpak0mqScDcjB/oJMuFqFZiGdJscqyTuj@Iy7Tpus2DEm4Lq@YGoapWUDQYTvlPAdlxka2qlQ/vhFIRxPG0jSFLGe6LJKZdQWIZui2iXAj1sGL84JymZIUNSVBKhpO7zZAIecjQkMOqLgL@UkG7TomMGi8ju4mJHoT1c41lyA/AeJAWAvRxGppVhrFN32e714eXVFOmWOjNeyNY8KysmCux1wHs3JwsKDCBREsvTFwalF4gtYrscnJvYrSyqSVOB6SOCiQQQjzhHi8prCzIY6U7hJq1uGJZOlTbaM2xUNOELLGgj0wamN0PPUEpdTgBGoQ1NhirHxJhvxA5BpGHwUlGSYVjg/Ne3qwP4Ho2TTbSXuxtiUpFKKZzzgvkhuxSegGy@REMqcUIrGrV50A4lhuXGM6KNaYLAqTFvoPKaa0Q7jTplVI0R/s0RjmiOUDXRwZNHw1x8n4xi8nEjOxQUHfzlN9EVNPCJYpYTC18DzdrGsLdOxHgigU0Qr0arDnOMCxLVJuhEkaEpSUI38ACdsJloprT2@rEAfKi1sFFjKyQum1w6TOQRqo4kljKZXFTFhTdsGWoPAtLB@7WoJea5eTwDu6mmAjtg@hBb6eI9OgjNf0nFMLGFwk1s1D7CjmabEXzjxfQ0kH@hidHGy1xfKdYsMDyilJAwZk@thVES38fIFKt0AfPip/auAqq4wdsHAxjclKh5TSs/5M6XMko0CiXkSzkumOnlee5qQBNaExefjQHFEkvk36mJtbk3sLGMkUcNnapCQPjfpo7T5KWuqKF1B0owZC1sLuOGAVNI6TOsaAnCSpp6mqSBwEndwhtWNAXfYQPZQJZHQbgO1w2tpwy@zrBpyeQwGxC8wsPuugnCQdIoBj9vB370g6esmMAwQcNcCnQvEFcFLnuInO1yCn0InPz8xMx4s3Kb5u@No0WQGX4SZV9cB0LHPtyiMkyE4M0EIOI9LG0K/m46aXszadGO5Dgv@XyYQAyq0EW4aXFlTAxtqzkuq7sB0q6A5/RaAYPG@UDaEmK6Z9gto66d@q0wQ/h0mTSgspxAYgFe5gaVM91AZLUA18aFSuYdiga3Mnv/pXSOWUkYxpR2cElI4zqXnuVGlvPm9eoNsKD7PzzWmEE9OuQPWVaBxmXkC41s1Eq/wtzLI1V9RlGz1kA5iJwXsjh6xuLjMetxiR2w/ZkWiCU1HSszU/e4WJCeQ4VFaoMwXQ1M0t941qR5aSRynqCrAt0XVwTRIgKpBL4BgNf4EUhJNFGvxXTLStKGsbMCMYJ0JHgD5JEIUoZjjPpXI44pUdClvbA65XyOu1N0DIxAql@/FYp9SmNVeQbka4I9FTZ2Btj6eyr4lI8pETYQOEREtPCEDDDtUkZIkUGPQZToNkcl4iNAJLZCPMyMBwgcN2CDeyyDcIzG71srS5qLrc6XWHRVYGFXyIhXDmmspVHOE8zHqzcx3Jf7egjs0tkMhE9zYapsHiQbNDrh4ALnVS8fa@cQFMamspDETDLVWvFscZdBpIVWW0qKx4LUywDzmDSCcpIoqwwZvIztjjUsg0odnqbWKqQsAKuidYLYCVLk/yVZCGgfFeLtshQ7VxHBxL9ORaodXkfUsqsGwSlboxfQ6EMk/eboyLOdsJdhknLjmooVSfC32B2yxxvGOMDuFe9eGGXS03RR0G9htwJ73LQjslClQE0S/nBE5UfBzklBxIGBpKZIxGyCaJlCVBArcYK7Bk03PmAoYsZjrc6@ndbr13OtgrTOYo6cP2Wu7a3LX7Uu4F1QKp3oH@TrRbxkYuyBf0OH2AiUSRldbrGQl4yaQYyg8skYE3W3dFdJ/09cNcKmiDexofEylQd2k4uh5n1wQxoigeXJFOQkbD6oHUQ89OghqogRNeEqAT0TpJdK6mU43QcUbeO@jJtebCSAIP8/ZU2Mmxz87RocPCAayz5@iEoZn@LSqx10narOhOvurwrOSyY5a7eIoGThNp@jiEs6joNnr@QZLk9G42HxGkR/gzi2oeGsf73HN9aNZbMhqpnqPJMfcz7QRfECBAiFVEwl6ed6SDkTzHYvRldk6TilJWyI5nZT1WohTMN@35d1RGuOUPIkmrAcFvVq6z18jL@/GopO4YSVBoNM6K12NkzVB4qmkPr5@3SewGVbuCP5fMMwVxxdqjMa9jnEUWlAS17tQGTNkdqYBKXi/h1TPVHkyALo2rCV7jIRK0ZeCgxlhI9oDAuOY@CiRCNpI7LuVbEwflBhrEKpe5lBHgGTGcKAM0uwzRAU86jad384jjOpkfh7uovi7nBN/ZEUZ1ZpDtsis98zNwZWI8Tnsnsf1ad1kq3Ko6MEKu@sad@zokstc8DQziGT5TAXrtEC669M/R0efs3X7oGlYo7TH532Er69AU7Qh1qDD@GIc/0C5dattpeX1c1yQ@x8xmC83i4P/nQwCNQAQP87bdIONsXsywukpJxCCi7MLSMLZja1hLEciF0BScTv9QVPRggYwpSZz0a3ToApIUnE87kfdpVcFl17H5HGN86Wg7HKnVc5GaLqgY4JZHeqwwSfocgG@T4Vd1nZicq8esvjqXtdXHkurAs4@LL0Y4Vq1RuteZSwk7oH95OgFx7oYX4TnxcoOqm7Tr61zXKzmdhzTssMlkggDSXD9wYYpOPhXWW1vetS/gKZ0kom0BQZC0WFCyJreFWm4KsrxbpJnL3p/1igt8xKc6MBCrAmWbW8nYomsDSFvljJiUE4iZe72uLD@2dYdU6jgvlWmGqN4KujK9QpL2mk2QDIhJYS/6EDQ@R@H@82wMBuV5MFabBIG26CzRKChayAESMhpw2CjTR0ZmaEzTD2XdUlcpDMhrSt0E6XrIiQv01dFRZSwhnDhBaz3JK5nqDeLL@lm/dKpo1koUO0W1B4JZCPuZAWPkvTEZwUPViaMc/BmgNQ7fM4EidoCg00bjeH46yLCUgjGK8Hodb5FODbmAkiVo2Oi9IgVuO99IbnogmHLeLtwoCxH7OSZW70QPZ@KWhOBqiYHrVHSbDzNGhOullINnumMinQAh5YqM@VnKD4imZWoQEiyekkhfzs@FJSWz@shzw8LgiElxA8eFSfW0wM0aPLx4ch9TFnfvbvMqTlMpg1YMOVRATZvKskWKoh1hDeA4VqPEEWKC8yd55airh8sRO3@6Ft29dUSKytJGy1Hzr6@HeQuhiok4tGiiNxpLMAdqPct5bSxx4hOdoLVcLnpfLnTC5voPpLF2uDwW4aBRKMghsIlH14AWkkWjpoE9mdKXXDQdnTNUsnEcpJdEALQaJRuIA0gqUKTPPcUWDowIetfDBp51GQBKpj5itCNvzVvPK1KIlH8U1Bpz@UynOKha6GnhWG2sl2me6qX@@KNSvQNnpam8ZSNtOug1L9SMfmGG1BianGMUi@HWNy3LuULTZVQSvFougXAbzAIPIyVQHZYBz6LzAIeV8Qxy@tzIEatd@HqEgY2hHY8RhiEzeBYZkxmbBDooyzSZTaVeBSa4aDKoPaVOnUlyZYigFYqTFVzEtEKxEM1TQunh1jqp3PNV7JkD8IU2tyY9aignx8WcOAlnmVmE2gZin3quAdUQfSVeMFJKFcd5aGopUZLon7mFwwjIBsv2gCVO8NFp1XgdFPFUEEZViYMUCDpjYE5Olk6xoOm7KzLixFSKFlrIEcc3RGLlnXscbirGM@5oEX/MQwrYZpp0NGkKo74NO3qaxWkOzZ4yDMd91bf0LgJI7lsVgGGpLraSeuMjyZhjrptjmVXLfFP4snAwQ2F55kHYeztQLHLSJAT48mWBlkqifjGRHfBWVrZjS0yLAK/VXnFdr@ASgD7P4yKud1GVA2QPOgJEYKvsghOQG55JcF5fFCKCoJ2GRJxRWFCNihoBdxs0ury1eD7G1KDe1QZV22h9ZCVMdkxwSebFUB8htXWVF9vVkbdGSIImwa03ArWfAZwZU9vDFascvFc4wiXaIPm2EpTNwuucJU/hrAER@OntoExy0nDUqQdCAEQzGmc3aR3TtWU4t6xjtCrkDIGqNTGZKGMVj1pSqmHvMerVoreuDT6miQABzq05XKJ3CpTObD27k5U5deBdfKOwLd9ot6n063nHHSExp2aBJfRf7YluGpY2iWqw/p1LM3S1ditA5tTyMIIqCZVLS1q736o33TJ2cKbAoDJPJQBxcVwesWk7B5F7GNHPBkN4jqsV8hnYpScHTXxDUIhMzYPEKIpJAJNvvLlZ2z0E6JHIemLDh4DwmPTBJu2DrheGzaySKApJGyjRzkHOHiHBaRQ8iIlj5RYTkCgwOmHsGwCSiE7xwkQlRDJidozK6Y/JKGq9VkHNDHQ5C@pkCvPuc1xI8tIS9sbmdfLcQD@8LDvqsa4ShlWao3w8c1skS8htg5oCKMsozSXSuU6HmknvGi7Vu5OOvcrNAztTi6I88ZxQBxv7PDw2VkEoWL7D1MgW9XBNOY5o7w5MQwKeJBza9dRP3rCCpGJvhLZlK3gQkYHa4PBDJ23j90ODFJF91OXpmlwkzQpCaTferbV@pyZ3rK7obQwIcONmRXsGQPuBOa31aAPJOqioNbYJWkFxQ66FPFEH85h2bc4YuCYj@Gl5qmd3ZEalzRAD86QYmqNsLeIxu@Xeybh4x6nOsF@vmSvIiFb3R82ilTcbdCi83TRXuCOtVOG5WN4wFqTjJwSsAUkKFy5Ku3BxzLDQSShlLJWrZwvTss0LLFVZhhY1jdLRr8YnwHCQZhalFmmpYbkRVAV0EUkOyozLyTTv5A55LMjA7EpRJYXiCQ@MncKEnl5QHF1IlqqvwIzwnoKAPGukIEhI4PjUsUtY1BSIGcKAHC93zyn1By0L2YQqfKqnsDeOONFLGhYGVIPMhBrBUMS5KO88icBg7LyibmbmBHCl4hHVj7c85LNuZYEjIs1CfbV0sQHSG@n8HpYN4KHtDtufu/NJaA80igsaVat68xkMwUHBuh4btocjdxwg4YqDPgOL7zF4pPlY0DLr/VbGpja0wEBwRGcCme/ux79YSTAayh8Kp7EgNQy6JGu4mQ5btrkVFfpFNsbiRye1iSeCzFGsrXTYDwp@3UwftWyXnPTOOl@Ic40m79qQaKqwIqrmGv56N2C@yvAvlBV2s2lpj9MElYEz59QmjlbZjCQNMKhmAGCJQMV6rPVvlQM3a6yLbbzqVRs/6OxOJhNShsokjSFaBr4qKqdaA6wZl5mDDbZFewgYiadT4I5tBOqMU8MVN1JugxkygQSRiLANZ1ad9xMvWVcHXApQVC1PLX2Rhe2QROA4oWLx/jCiNAYqwOxNXii2J6IBaecK5BhAExoE/@gxmWm0w04EDwsXiwbltB3KVM@JLu6NNrSnRTSv3v9oUoDvmI3YJRPxjBKGerOGBmVI9sQ6CUGT6uMGszQVl/GU04FIQ1OyNh2nl8MeiWKudQkEI1mgPaPXSblflw9fbs3QG/ZGUquduAYDOuo8SIjvtKiqzLoiLUyvBurC9FkyLQOyJ1kaIH8O/HIlosj0AcFEka0TcLhHgYFT1zwi1/QbaG0sqvWho6H23ME8gMWbT5zu60pismIpH2obzAJdW8phfGqmDFfrmkGSzVLJIYuxd23iryuxJSkXRw5ExIt0SnqoJWM7vCMXIKhjR80LK@d/65EMHTlDhuPytQORRfThTDaAGFkNseal7D6iso54eM86VGe2XbtkRU1ITE@kkvseGe8kZ3LzZGSXD81DlHrVmcGLSBaMC1inwS4NcGoli4OO3EBY4Gk31158E8im7XBhXRIL6/8QiINqNFcOoGhWfl/zzW4YxMh@PWUElzac9@b7AuIzvVr9CjeTusNqCJpgaOP98VlBOP80DpXon5RQ55lrXbZIZ02sIHr@aCECoDoNgoGLZV7RykXMFHTC/@YmPGAkfDWdRXqDaakxewFx7Z38ATuH6ghYUgZ7ZRzW4ZQ19IjQ5utU@KGT5jpY1blip@Fa1@Zzirhe683VtgOapEhLk8rSJqUtt1bmgWgm72DsVMqTzG@rACFadtfoO4cFOsMAefcFJ3ZJEO88aJTT6ibNQW/s1Exsc2umXcjQAkCX2mirIJmpCvQRkIAZGcdGXmDkMD5XUZM2O5znkDu1uYoRmpImviXPcQZqaxKkSc/RR6Nz8mR3dsCcHBZNr8JW1oAnGarm0TKNk/pDw@7qrALFVL7wXSOdyHu2sb2wkmTQ6M8n7SSgODyoM0HiJrWT1m43gvoimK5gzEGBdAkFH2wAZhF5jsjkqwMmujb9OmHxJh5XZJqLiqaiUV1lDTUnc5VhQ8f2WJjUTvq6a1nFBOs@b5EBprHcu6Y75kOucHE6DWaD@Ti8N3ZSNcCBnHnoSi7M/2RWm8Vymhmgr6c1cHHtVAKRWDtiJuiX1nONp/Bpk@7@oaMm4rNjSzZPrxuHvNjsXaR1glMPr2YTe@L0PqTHTEahMKqfY3yW2vtnOQKQ8IMZ0hqhY54gH4OQT/jq0PMkpmQQB6VHBys1i1i5hU3ChEj7onbMLXOeeC7lVhstZiTQKlhMDok5kkmFeIf/B4DbeQmNERYYujVoBMqeJVAHioyMV7zh4@XxDKm6Nm7G1iiZaSZvj5YyYoPbLKRsm4/VD3olqoCLdakW/1rGaGfdTVljxExb4dxJedDE76aqkzzKtrUt8k5nwkBZQQ4XB0Q2kYkKEwD3ISHuIyB0154yN4kHCqo1hAdURJT6RhM7JzkRpI56Hdot2NyKx2liN4FwCq3sa0lNwGhIikLOSeR40SXLtAQYbIBgaNOVjnxTIljpQavrYWrqGOVWWnznQ3TzPN9G7ETSjEOocvDPOr0bkE0SH4dPDBD82jEmt/XgAE@ZK6IHTkCWnSilWmA5ikRmfqHZEuj1tr@gG50I9jaoks6T7j3sKSRBW30Tm4UT80GnvaW4nSpZrCH4wyp3@dQNGzoHC6VO9r6kxuP6jucGDXSSZrhYqCYFYoNBY9BOpa2jhh5ax6JNScDQ3seiQdi1rFe3WwU1MVucaRGNGy02PtTwZoIbylCDJDvMfTwaN9TYCLehNdtsvfSGbrdppkfgmyNDHUjoH16bek471tl3X83OwPyQfSw19rjgw/FdSb6X@iB9Kkhlp0JK68m9JIkZcJxEg55j@wtBea2xZ8FwDMNqTiX0PSBe9fdwpZ3n0dFvoPe3QkeP9AHC4O5YNdf0WNvsubqjTUkdeZai7nxIDPXhKgCJE3AqOm14obeC02gQb0ZzmoZcICSsUcE5fpTE4nC1VBkblcDnYkQryNZY1VnVxMpjQ0551sP5pzbUZXf5EdEqbdXWjrRWZUKE6aWUeAmrysV5bcgf/lFdGgAHh/5fmuE6QGO48WN7zdE@acpP3Wabk9pNYIE5QLd1ODgifCYXFeD4xXQySLV1jNWArV7Gxi0rr6znuESWrrS1MLasW6SDMBgcS49d6DWc9tmAyLtW05G@66ayv23PWoKtkCsDk0u3LmFLyOL1DIZO9qyB3iZVHbVqfOyHZ0Tbb5s1CYIMIRkyPBRdCejYBXaBWhiEgR8fXNEaiKhY6GloWxhmdYSb7xMJTd9rH60Xf@@7RI4oJQm38c547wSoRNZoQc5mynXrymKrxYRqOseQq5vKvjsGCNAvJjA4pxGIG2kaHMxqdRRe8NVlnWYD99VWRaMi7QxfZojr0JE6Y3qDHtw3mIEn4CgI7dvucjw4pDUo8FqyiapCtNAUG/JgHM22cfXcWbGgsT/VBLixZtgEfOxHBZRWQhIhpctKKBygco605FAibf@GNQe3ulNxdUu5XgVzAcZmfE7fHFJueUCY4DvmhM9IXEBLrrxax8fkr8fTf1iznQZmd440C3We0prKT9P2ytJpnRxpjRlKo@6q/TxUrssYQtniNK33gQnweIXQuCWMDb@USgQnaSfoeviLRRsjSW8ZChSDiJ4toDKYBIaCrna3tCEEd6ZG1AkTBMroVG7@vdoLozIO3KVVBIHKWW7Um51sbJOZt6agi8EkaUWkeJ0bGtuzZVBDev3qSp87Y50QFTqV18CNXaXx6zvUhPM8WCTIEzVJs8CcXJgc@9NXvLm5eJ4H7HxUxLHCnUgqlqxpspC4ymEV6RyNtrmiYcDlLyW440rU600KJoJGP9qrQKombwxwKU5cyqOoGjD3X8xiA@32eGuCIjOs6Se5H5t7EkBMRF/nMGG5Sg/4SIQC94Ro8/oLu9XXFBqGlKJ4ih/R2rLSF@tEkHCnPOoIXOTlC1E02EUVMN0ddqtUMJzLhuB1LX7Gyrnf44Ic35yUs6zpkG01ycIXqvbeXBabS@xqsIAIg/VLHa0kVpkSQwFVWPUL@TdooRrHU60yZ25FSaxIZmHRr4jMVf2QTod82fG9Puu4fGwgwFbLwUmy4KkDM5gapysGwTpeUaEtps7SYKymCHXHM/vB9i@37o3KaZlrSASGKMyWgetjMcKgZt2zkLtC9qWPMYtfItfh9FqwL5QFPcaKACKp2OAgpGa4@CpIPYK@NmVE6xQrQkTXzklj3W0koyUTggnenNDZ1gKN@K66HmD91gRoTW@q5WgGGRPW2Wj1sDopahrlOzn1elRNaQf3EsPJcK4zdlEAH0sfR8eQmccA4F9jIhsmWrFbZgn0kjvRyFXEDpObYOfsVYk0iIxdEzOz@k9jQElax4FHQEo6HL91JkLK9dFe3F5sQbJklShxxE5TBxkr/pM7k8EiT9IrS6Ll4rhrUcjPSMZiltjS2rL@Tx7WBndZcSECHy8opKE9GxTQqaM1S2@99wpFOCdHaVrLPLEzTE@4mED8O7F7Vw06YeqkvRmyiLLAfN4gXOofuBRi4vFoF88tNMmSQBR8hxavVw46vEOuZwWk68Y3owIAe0VTzkhkIGQbMqxT8eszIDhyDBPRJ7YU@R9eqiQUPu1UYcxoQfoDkkxpiRHnqBwo0d8Jpfk0/sFORpqMfC1Afh2ni6rtc8t4p/jMLrViGyBdEq6C6IucSQV2A4MFEWgQ1cs2b/axWxUMw4kyt8ZysMseyQEoUSQS7DqpqFhGa4uRGFopRYZ34RAaCKEVyiGPr/bP2naszhNm6bEfjgl@S@zMyqQAj7Lk9C3wHZzwYNm6Ik5pDgLQvuGeWNRHw1mdUT1KM2zM6q2dBootycUb5U9RFwP5/ONm0Ywmzr7xcJcmhBXdxLvuQV4G5bDyYCqTSp53Bqwa73LxvQ9MrPWxmPERLElo8OdeQibd5XoEJUb4OhLc2j4pc1zGz3gjCc7vGuQkLZC6PvGx6yqj8rBDkF@zJJt7eF@jJUbNUzYtRLAMlWIErogrGI/dWK25XoaziY0JVB5FnpDRhzbn/6G10bfFnKGRgYmlqVjWIztwMsBoaLrUTA3R9ror1NLkNCe2yTjlSL@ifki2BvSaKKG6ieOCeaFt0EXP@bmraev164sg@ueppzC1lJsljEp3bL7pvTIl7ZOCKlkFAvFOBsPLllyuOY6mAxVr7ZkohurRJig7NkVF61nGi5Uc1obSR1KA4xmgcMx8LoANFekf7Gk7VFhQDoFHbiIPMn2WFKUeZRtXdOas2Bvt@L7x5s3BYOPl03NJ0v@wFGtfEFppGCcEWhdErLMwKp0rmqYF4gNl2NjpclRYbR6y9xRmwICcnHpfOVi9VSHz1KJEgauF55IYir@OKfBEq0lWwVF6TRPBj/OZ2kdZD80wfIB82C0iBlqPynHNi@s2xXpJGovL6hVEGBFHHYSy39uGNqDi7jzgGQHiWc@nmNhi5zqzolR6A0bhGRlG6kz17/pee@3fJmtBxVHgevZehTzsw8QoWckqdO4YlYRhKyyAvsEZxTIZ7dtaGhtsek0vWJKQ4jmqN9gTesrkRFuHbCkRKsQy6fX28RSsXnwNKuNeBpJO3c3JlDAZSiIBznPDApA1SH@1/A4dLGnQrnj/YDvBAM2Ey4Cze0HmFDTczgm7CdxK6a6ahGjtRLqGOSGpiKjI3LVgNVv/72ppDDcneLereBWSWe1cp4n4AjXMz3cT/TPZcukd10aBoB/18FpNgHysnaX4J5Y/D93MmuuJkl5ZeQIjNn7j4w@pzEDUzT57yBiSWprXr4mzxyY3KvqINxI7@jiOq/TIRTAN9wgWLKy096Qev6N/NgxyeJJ6ztXIGRGwqzO86Gka8gqEQWVoOsTWDipTGv4BCqSzgylbMXwr2PDa4wOb@BabWI7Cnr50aD46DFHFcZm8OuyVI6mJvCwj90POgCGUWV1y3qITqTdVH0DNTyBfSqJKWgrhJKozkrfmqjFwWysJbeWdJR8XOul4BU@NJMp6QuxB8k6Hqio0qAbuLOjMezBqB7YJfaMgfJybggO37D7Zth28172uRRVu@E4jdgYKiZrMSdMJfCvS/DFI1tYuJUtiBsFSSHUFrzGRrV3IeA/RBYrpKAZ@NJNRvjCU1SfgX1mGk0LmktXcYbm87p/msysYLkxmyXEK5aU8OTlBpQPpmKVBbQCu17QWyE5TZtN1pl1Xb7WI4yp1LnCig2iB5gXInWLMY/WaiqkBnnvnIHsAtVmohtDBlke4M2UZqfQent64rtQxhEM8GhedHxzdOHWIlQi/eWGeJDiuKmSUs2FWkHTsMtyQaNaQJnLhheMyJtQoSesmFm6G3tqj2yiIdd0J6SRi4iEKb@gQXkMcLlVibopYDBW8KQWjq/WEl/PYwMZ1Qxqq5jNTqHYj9djy3Xg9fWUswPmOQxrrIyYQ9JYJD/AFU3@QRk21kanVE3FtaDTESh8@kC0PhjX8C5FvmJ4EJkPuP4exFeO/7bnRUMP7zRujhtZErw5OSc5PB5MuznpGsrX9xQOKygoFxsZxxj2xd3dUUkqqZbJy1IQ2E8rKqnJcrjj4BYUvaoX0CXAQ7DwmBM/lPJKpDXpcD2tuYVarR7e0ttuJbdD1IhEFGIGNY70Vo6glLiSObVtxLyGxB3zDIa4PKYWM4Ce4AsBpDEncmUhzSSEJhYceKFDM1/ZR36qNMuIBz0WBjOnGsUwB@vv4wGNvpZhwylGNxKzzfGmmrC9R6@FU5oKvMGty95WyAg8DAkf/jPT20K0pCYdoN2bMFGFAbHCCFtWY6f8kxGVJr2qOxK4WT2oLdAFJCRIORJCqIJwbBWJDaoK2u5zUiVEMhY4f57GNxZofZrzb8DyZ75cGuDAQ2Hgu2upwODii05mVDdl5siib65qmS9fpbOW@QElJOpcsGCo47Vh1viij6KwgsVY/A5pdXSNWX91ISG07WzRrO@yXoCjvwVRY37DqJuKz/s9sV1fEulhSE/sBmZctcc0gd9dqZZEOC2hqXWtCG/oKC1odMpjUTo5eXdbr4ISAhrWzbtaCe7ordXCYZB4CqHOORAQQmbOa5LrT2gRF4YcNbgkwvOV288wtoQCkmmU7x7ySuIBk3aDpzXiCZNII2qqNFEfWpZtbjtbwGFeqiX9iO594ieS7Y1lYyYisKxzdbXrXBEQlBlY6NBPCX8K0cxWCGIm2@uknNBEn9J6bKaDOElX1DJB0ONvYL@u9tBtYZqNxBR5M3f1EKitNa4kMsDauJWJVwF/5VEWbodKvuq7mHJgzUX9KQwikRjCqmeUH1xjcUjY@Nm6uoUrvXjXpZBBJOb1YoP0i7LAG53rH4rxWoJHXI9Y2NaE08EsjwomJkrmndIDQiNlPoV@douId0gRcrTM3pbnc3Lh@AHR2fDWGKW0jreFc25HYd9bMuIgrBxrdwDLSJn@fuaZZLNHRH84yAUY40hyMWC0guqgkaTBe9Jltv1Ct2VRan@wRSgRaxe6Mj11wsZFH0LG/WYodl6lzZx0IOPNG0Gvm9MeHAa5Yx2wLzxkMNhltP4J6S9l64608mSrLEXmd7Mu4ACPcS@REnqfzm4KKc5@hN0szbAIAyu9K2AI8c6LFUjKq99OeZe7NRk4s9ukmcjFoAYsCJSlM0TtAaEOtCirJeqpNqvDs4gIWZIwkesuzhvCSq4IENfcMu1nybGp5jKtjqlPr01noKFwFW@MpON9mPptNce0osg3S7Ki2GTPoig4oLyn3w9jE9adkJBNzh3JG91rKK5NZCWvXHMvW8JuaB9w1aiaz0KWw/uy56zZI7DAWGi/alsCgZzHbJh7JXciZQ2BE2qw16ceRRG20WUT5IpssNpYKCQbODdoJzcGP0rRWNfqVTHg416zdhS7CVrBIZ4iZtAaFokMF1TJGBh9r57WKGWPzD9pbKIFvDRI5BItlpyUGwEJa8E7yxBZ0b0XKHpC1LAlOaRd7jmMTjMwBcubCG2BiIVrA1cRHTOzwTkwZagbWJYa@SLWn14B4LbuFtTEvyJabYieEAJXcmOnOZdENSoK18lxWPvLFilYCvjdIgBoTB/TXtvcdMgZOWTDCTydlR0l3telykKTVuOcWq1D3jkNfe2beHj7Eu76jS9InndJITnWXPUN0@H6TEvddh2wy7lUWmPR2fdEL3M0UiYLYCxapMiqhsU69K3IWLvbL5FUQPCwlrrBHm/XK/9dnKonBTc17R5ma1VGvWmdCYYbAGugfS842rlJ7pGEQ9TCjXluy1tXtdLrteMl@QU05FIe/cfWaPqr3SY9cvEFcYDL5PYadK6@f2SNge82oNZCRusdYtJvnAzKMe@UaEoqxsbAfGaeJt2BVgNvaOnQd8KtEOgQTs9CI7nQYPaVqRbqSAgXqyAH8bVx86jB9zLQ3BRbwY@KBnkorB9JCtGQgro1DT@e25GWf1e7PcDmSJYD6yKIBaafYtSAwp5yF@Rg4KYkzVLXcDflcT7GS8cX4S2tpX3/wO@kyLGEZaU4fB7@NNXQpH4FLDqkC03u5kx@xxjmzPZRGoApeYV7HiM1YMDvaDo@jUTgQTkleuQZS5DsaLJPz01qzaVd3miAssM37Wdq8qeuZwgQdBoAhr7i8HDW6eJTAaEUTbFODrwCOOsZIBfprMkIj8aSTSMue0XbXJsV1Z7nG7lAwkAIfQO6gXhO@AmCKfLwITYUxc4/BY5r6TmSU5dTqVJVqZ3/oAjMkOA2KQ8EKPtGwn85BTj2Sda2v3@nVOVvXZQkZE3q164IQS5RPPmpQDNT74sDCUk/s2FUNB1xNZcgb7B4q4oNWKc6AtY/KZFxyxeslkwMlN3noLOnQvCxjX2TuA8OxFCkT4UDoKoCgNiUu4NM7GaAZSO3YMS/VM2PcgzEvIBHJXK1Memv8rHOSUv6qRGsCilU26Zpm8qTrtTLmLT0YnLok@8Y43z0zX7nQ9wqEOBvuEuMJSQ6dTEcETk4nvGzsuEBvAHktgVbZlBfDbKCS@XAXi9YgekVnewTdhgFvS0E3FGPwzBtuBWvAwoRXPNpUmKJzFs3i@klBxorS0I6gWRcB06mXlXjoDmJHb0U4y@sRAU0NH10k0Jd1psNwl@i5VqC0nBSmV0YdP4ZPsk@y3uohU5D2iQhiRASSgROCP4e5WKFWRseZaQspGuQC/HyBqFtyoBCcUf7ImhWzOkqKNHzqR48TEBCQx7aplEoadCid2bGTdAUCAr0He62p0E0kOGh26@CoqiMQSi9AigRJ0pua3Hp1NKzC8XDmzlboR2I7ILCSl1Q6FOA15eseIaYcR7caoRa5uiarVnzZ9YmtwAzAueBIrm5PeKDiTrNYGuA6VUllM7J@h2pKzzQUBbZSDwBu1ayzdWnlqqqMbOSHgSs2ERdGWzROsT4s8XUjuJsefXQXvepMHyM552X70L3QgHnU@DZ5gri6vE7vYGIbUiUYAmfomZ74jXNNjXmWOPjxjjNc0BVTy3XrDvFBwS00B1ZKAAhyJlDbpDlBgjjWhW9AM3oG3Vx3LkTnnVoteiDxtdZRElru1FDMcbfRp5EDzKMYW@Le3Nz2sNLUNML0DYG0mxqqarKk@rTocRvdQ85vbhA2H92KOypoVvnWOml9vA83teFDWqG8aonbSNGkAdjLPsNFU9FEW0/MOsPJzKlYiOTKw1sIt9Fh3tTK1@dcSXturp0EqlUGgXWMwVnTek32y5tbgY1X/icmBR2RS3uEN0PktcwgGt4wyAtwZtLtDgmsnqG9uj1W5yqrbAlagiyKsrLrFUZVjfVZ7Yol@WrKy5ZNHjKLIIYt6Kv9aqdNbuVEBe4uUYaStwnMBW5Fbtlzkq80pZdkw@GW1RxxIt4RKis0TSE0YA3SE/NbnO6egZJ0q9EElN@xKru5Ge7M9RMJ8zKx2lDOihqsqdLF0c3ghwRln5o49j68UzJvGOTyGLOXVgYLvekst@a@i4NcC/MsgZ1nPavcXe7wrniLfH@HuWuc3XEpesdwOso1U@Wa8wNb@eWb6E4dbh5mpgtVKqcFQ0zwhkpn7NgNd1Ey5gZGu7WBedxoNxqPST97eb4LKGbHCUtyE6TojKCFOsukixGB4M7CbMe7Pah2WB/JrdnPqDzYNWY2HXpYlIWhLjs2D2yEMO41wJEqDGPSF7A2PIqgGcMaPbeJ2RjyPSAcM8GdCvsnuv55oilGlWJtauSZtOxjcAdBHiIzDVUcOfmaNFg17u7HAW4EePP8ljBqYB7ro/W1@a13NUZCc6aEgSD2NcU6kplCHOCWBonBz0Sk7tg57goxwQe4reHSrIBaMlKgKa4I0AGZBjCVfODPZ7ljp6BG1rVJbu5rE59txlZom/nMxG3kuwMj959lqju3Ds66rdalatXAZqTvbsjr2JZFi7ExYV8c9aoms/mJBbTCyzDs5dpa9lJdqRbaaoYUonQn9qKU4dnE11vFN6jQXD/1xua@nMn16/l6jF0nD30fabvJMg8GvkEbHnJh7gCOz@zYcS/ZCs@nvoD8I2uf6xB4K9Eg6DRHgTallBfdHhxbgHmo8RSSJ1huhjSTX5NeoHYnzH4jx2Ypc@684lBZ1szOD3WqE12/L1PgQDqFSXBD323dHaxHd/058L2fRvDp9cSbE2tXS3bn66am2Yi@vbmRr3uIfT/nvbYuo/htO/HtFZa4aZNvdIdaZy2aRNoFqtONEHevmTCMHZ7ZBHiRsVsREVx6nl9rDJwSheO5u9caAcdVPMQdsqco3eX5BPg4ri4s1vuvMqWG0uRF4cxYCfXwmwzzOpqz2/ro2V@LGQaqoVn/9Ei@LunkbW51K7Yx2oUUk1e2y1ev0HZrzDHxo5M7pINNEA2Y/kW@rnZtjTfTT3pb1cY6L0xTXolbrZbzeObj2eYCJ4yXh57w1RkQWMghYZH8geU7Y1F27kqTCDoYLtpM97SXCDQuy1ZpdCeHykRPvOHw0pp5WAZvoOQ9FHnXvaoCgZfsWsLFIkzw@n66itwNc18GCl2fxMvd/MOTo6y@ddB1OdVFAVyFYy/Netd1mt0mRPtjYGHDc1d0zq0XYDizMOFtaOEkt6VHHLs6HHLcm@TumgzuXBVUB9xDbNM1QEPd3Fo3igoK1Acwg@EEhxAVz/GjBEAd/QXR3c1Pk3oLr9E5QbeB7Zsp3xDJg1WkGL8Oc114/0WCbh4E5vFBrcasNDuBxhwRvhip9fAMXUTRLaguD8/bUhvA/yYpOrbeSAguwMuskHT5FTHeH/JSIuhiaNLz3JRyx9N6TWQ5K/8l7kN/rKOM3@p8NygsH0/Unf7bRnp1tnIDTF0GzP3/bNBraSdIBqpiLyzZVZbuw453vc3aDHcPFyVaS5Gze8R4VzKC8own3S2e8ApkoS7yl5m46x3m61N3vYFxlM@u0Gu/n8xdF0162em7AVzH9Sf57pEOs/J3Pfl6mdi73@8pbjfCPWaAi5zdG5rerrB2O7XpRm1Zk/TrEHe9L6IshhOd1JHueKTuwlkx5e3S@Baed@DulpFr5u46qOsh1Zcpoy233vCaDWUXIjMGXr2t5aKvYlTyhbjO5HY4XHBuGw/FenAFzMGxg9uhh5BVl5ND1jp7tyiYZNnPY0e32cCOxrcJS37sGDdg3GW8jRpKkjiFDn00JnO1K5Zrfdk1mFs/MuTwSoVVVw11WRzauOBq2hCsyPDyKAFmkFUcb@Si925kBYkM/bJndMPlHWvZgFW7Mdnl6w1wq8bXCOyfZQmzUu3I4S38yMawlwkgSr/W47@0mq/jxut7f01qeWakdx3GrgMyhnZr6tX6HKSc6NhT8TVq6opzZi5ziaXnFlPb1GpYMES9cWouSCtPLHjrfrVzXnFG3pTWq6T@1I2LK4@ZisPa4Iv1XFxuJjUl5Qobd4y7Jeawh5PsWZlDxxntEYxc6sh0M9oZQoGEaJy7S9O2OKb1pVxr5ZoDPITi8pDEMoIsXrsXPboIlgx2F7q6x01qb9RcNwwY0sw20tn40bpED9VZXSiM/f2XS45Zj9yb0WKe2e1648zXR2yCwaJzEdrc/uLBSo2QS0PdHp246rd7XSXmbqgbUwWpyyCxnagxZ3886L0sQmkth70Jmq6T3xfmu1JG5MmpdoMjh2H8umqCN3WLKhcFrX2y3uqFmPvjP0h2j3vnUO8BiMeaPt5YnsRhPOwOh7@fl54lTJm7ystqBJdlEF8fcHXR0jhq81wGkRLNOhPnrkNAAFJOJl1oj8BKOv4WaaQb2llUJZy/nHPddulNXHMZOixYoTTn4eli3bIFE9d45paov4yYkdrq6EmuCQyU029Y5VxQNTPcANmaTXClYKq9f28SdzVCp7WtJ8VkZPtQKsvEWc7GUTqm1Ym6dq/khcGlscsQeNDVzWYP6LgaOWvb6DiqLTqGDcsVAJQ1hkEyOuaw1x3NKuBrmT4T5YK0cUUp3pCBSGv/2HJqYSrLup5HTGYnVBkB@GS9OCzlvNgJwsrjZd80z9ZBM/2wNmhdHaeu3KrMIWStPFbQVq4jEHa4mXFt05g2OuQOaQ1ks@Xe2YB2nHwnQ58WdobMZNQOiOza0tKSkz@T1FBWGbQ8yUfMR5zTOW3AtoVB7fBIIIvv@LUko9lIMIFM7xGeIuMH08CNVlJXvU5YtmgqEgopDyw4qyVdx9rFEb33oRPXDGlropHItt6BZ8KNhmAjeB6tuHwzfrkwgr8x6u2wZsk0hYArcZISOApQt0aeFLRbx3SRebfycJlrdUxTi7l7nEF4T5OzCMIkBtItS8brpDZrjvhg1gsFYDSGjmsAIF4jx20VlseTrNaA7oirKf7ZnVD6NQRb/Tgb0I46FlDJJl3TmfNz9MJVUmUwN2smtX3OiyaZY03mLBI9Ra/@v@ImufwXPSxAmoVx6no3lkw4junGSi3SMGZBpb1FF5J1axIVkMCRWMyzVWHna9lFhxz3zKHNOa82xZz5dBKOBLj/kFSoYL@hVnNtmBYqQ/jGcFHUqAIhorI3oeXVcqRSfn9i@eqJe2etKiYnWLrdw5G/ovjUFiF5DebsSldA4XE03PIUwACu1JE9B4XcaYeLkS9exFu/dK6bPAgADHPYGv89/5mMYH0pjTckoQqX567XYtIaCfJ4Fq0ij3H8mvBvqQFkI07ozYJUPWsVzRQStbvlXVibsV3bAre0iOPUlVQohwJF9T9pHHa4vdJwVyXgkmteXtnlv0UUtElFEzQKFuB6xyquydOcnTbDV6n4tCEjZ6usWZIun2CvLi8lqyOZ1leFRoNQTZLO0BlUMsRNGHU9w7xplajr5CZpw20rVy0ZSbCnk757NdV9Tzk93iovuFn2Hbp8UnQloop@seSTUNHPtm9aywwD7q2NZqMfLrQro1kNCv3NWV2IulkxxA26dXOftmFBNm2r@vSCPViCss@5td7YPuyy@qOunArwljVyLcAmQQXNMgBeDpZrgZxKhSl447hIUdZMepbGAs1ATsREtpOKoxcEHwEZK@xah7Sh2JFKqrcjWjhTzo8XTUbvK@thEYiVOeJkKurnBrcN/Dx3x8qHE0lueQeabF59lcRDMORiYBuGcW/JTwKcNsrzpZR23fxDywi1uZt1sx6OVcsjoCPmt3A8LhNrrZm1pI4873FhQa8aPjc9vB1WMBQ7hncK6qWtVDJM8IrccpXW34QpJz1kRJ3gqTqgQ4HoU1MnMXmNNmKT3HdMyxckkYkfjPQvEypPGpHDvqlnZsN3CW01cOGgaofpIZVEhrwBJZNKveWPQb@rkBxV4ipsxXHLQOf2iLmtr16n2SSdiBnTNgh16llcsvOCA2oYix2OJjFsryWSHJnkoCyj3REGKXhYcS1GKob8z29mdlsixM2zbL3l1BjlTlQS@1UsJT5ijxoNH93hPC6gpVBWcID1LYp7lxzCp4FTrq1LSNdsnRPUBhee3ByxcGDMwVQs@cQpBFbKwTAXG3xd1qv8ywCF7Zi4zrw1VcTgmJNxix75UEc3LKxS@wlcOJqFbNpZ1ZJLCGzPVYVkWzNczmeRZLR28hsB4LZQv9FIFktY6Ih34rULU4gJGqtbv8FPxgeqMNogBwRA4AWuP2klT1xxx6hPpTTo5oHtEEksko@DnJTrBBxqDCalBWTeMJhm3HgVwFDaY1lnsnUCUWIOABTxcExtIJhASjDPKskrM@YZCExID7bLj5j5jpEZuCym6VyRF2UeVHWxTW18kuWSi9@cfjvM/1rbaBRMbi0WnKahsbGeDxITi91ihWiWh8aSyeGbg509CNylmdoKy7aZ9kpi2@a5Dj1b5NvSlM8IEMwSg5vEzVA/CJsYu@qQS1KiccGyAF48ZNkOb3MLj3HQqK0LlUTIoG9oXZ6ILieeWTsqHWJUrKT7rpceH6SonEa/rDfRdrpcF0U2qL0CSixYn2H46mC4084FXb5DwR4M7U2uumGqouvLvHOhoYiYiCM8c5s6Ion7@lKlKW/TaAGuo/fajJVZrdImasqh5cTd2kNOiwVNx8DlgOIruwHHdgTcTlOZBobe0@jj6QzsdR7HZDX25RZ1mzlOe11tU1agtLXvBSf/XFGZmxCGq@yd644m4GYMdqbfUugfd7jQ4gMBDDzeFwWg236XVuwomwXzH2AWXD3UFg5GaqJLvYJAA9zcYl2GCW/8IYe9Vqs7er8xWmdygWrDBxVaYu0ur9/ZlDcMkwfFJoeDW7yEAaDFaHU8XrW/lW/MUhkBkBDJCoiqadU7EbIVh7uOS1iNsad3m@Z8y6hB5cnGaqlRv7YGKpastl5MwvP8CBouFKqro1weOtvZLqk2@QS6LST1OM5xJ428ALA9z/BgVNXIFVNKsg/9j3r8O0slE@KkKTYhMwCVr5kZANox6@8N@4Iaklk/eaYPvrlFrYagv9d2P@SXwvMc4dUNT6kbaKnSXPBT1@cpba6s589OSxnhAGnvChNCuKglGxTSx6GV0GYPzi4vS0u64KE4eJkUlU0Sethd3Nw813ZYXRsStVRrARiuud83m/rO04lm@GCpgPVrgeGPVrEKpp2ITaZzquYPdfjQTH5ZyzYs60Wb0SXB5WtyeAmb1msuN0xeJzlwznGIFwSuw8k2kl8hphw3Cl5b0k3FMLfHa4GQYweWMgqPEMl6@CyN2qIMV4KkE8Ot1V5Ghq9CIn2gihPgWas3H90T/@c8qazKBQzqqlmpA5GxyJMlAYDs@olnd2Y5s15UZwZHXOaFuNwEfrU6qzeF5ZZoVo@im3oqnAdZtLljboAGh7omeNA5KQtAjQT1i5LMynDXMxMOOUHXd/SIRP1lLIEn9YE0rewoHAJbA5lPrwSnbEibR/jmHveZM0VmPo2jxMf1TXSbAUksgbhnIYl@vR9gWJpT45kwczKKnlItJyTgmlhEDD3kDcFsJcHFEJ7IIRygvUCtrQSaawNwUH45IhYkRQme29RMYFfJwE0AAoVhlIv7Uc4RUDWSCx/DPFmhvMoCRqAY5bXKjjQbPcPRoGee1l8bCKNy6CxGGR1ZB4Bxa/@45K5rDQWIvaQKijRgx0nI2CZijN2UoLFkYO4oLYGu2aPPJA@/DCE2dg07SgvM5ZrWv29FoHiJXx8iwE3pJMNvJf86RK01zLj2btFoLGvYVZBJ1UWZWTM4eHnqzUAS5p6b2/J14ACwd1EiLvg/tXQIGfklU8uagmcdkIh/Yxu31q3pJnwZGkq2ngu6QfUIlZtEGDMir9ieqsCOCmy6//WsEh0jYnv4l5i5wv8dammVCwD9l4jcK2ulUi6td@3GTMDQwv7T2LQGKKMp/VRKEhZTTl3HTGiaGqxY6obTfGUi7IVt9NRNqJrh3h9OmvKgGwXdvvUVh8LHdHFFdjfY9oWWl2pV131gdYCsY@y0oVVebSJY47ZZtTTjJEnT1OQ6REUh64xWqOseuoGkPhVZ1Kaa4yHqeXojus0gkQ84o4Sdbfh9UOdJO46NGlaguTw6s5ULXWroqUeN5vKltGVr3m/j1jKJDqE8Up9rzO8qsK5mxYzZbOVu6mvx03W6brAhSDsA8smwYPkaDh6tV2ndSBG0n4yBhktHyA152Fub1X0RwbzmKFE71F@zEQKQ9oXLUEF1qYVl0AwDo29uoWyK0RdAD@D07qx305k3IrVkrrwcU9glDi9Pv5qJbhQM4/evufnBUb4kXi5m5@6szdSIG6EvM4fXqGtGB8NuAnWuAhivLbujtF0zy4UjE2KDZtQezWji3PEepqPcjkkSDHJApJdKMYePh0x84t1UyklfozX7wSXr2exwOVZ8KXbjaKCjx/Q2LUgSfMDftYDvmVB9eP1Ql3AcvaXumHyqwEASdy3AYVJ2bKXlh7WsZjCdFbSNnzz3BYYL2OY5I/KcvOphMzrjW3u3tixa1jor6k204msWUzFPqEq50nroPPbUzLiW49TgYNGucMBGAnC2wFSlUxh810VoMjADoikKiHRZr@kAl@gEShwq3RkpvkwsoVmuTocT3dlnaDWsuMlEoA6a4Rfq1/gpYgHTHXMXZrdez86VSTV1HuTaYU4r7I7uMGpyXvV@FOAkSBSeuYY1L8TkSmY7Is4VpjL4nP0d3bQd44m2672@z3uwnBlg4yVFUAnQWScMcmrTgZR8v@8XRLlsF867PpMXWPq6br2XY9wgU/WAYUL2zHUMHzDNuS0P/empogdhfGYnvlTWNooz7qImr6AAmmRTARtXL4YFhD1lhZw9kozHlL0jOwQ79Z7Em/zGQkmb0uOJVD24raxEL3DHQmCD4fUMjWJbIdERajZRD2eUV5oc72YjwKwGUuCu7V/U/qbSIj0PaG2Mm1x5gmuO8FFYdMFjLHS2QMEu60jSlBDBwTDdA6jBumxdO6llI@YoU1Nzk@N8dTs59LVUIGl/OWLLDBHrFxDWSqHhyRghjSNA/RsGLZZKII2Ez5I1pPeyPznVgVPh5pE5NAZ3y2OHI9qyYe0LAAd4ncwrnhFyNdz8M@of0hoTPccy22oOnBnqR0iRr8vheqaOSNjjXci0txmdgKRGglU/Zy40E1zbnXCQN16bBitl5eay8xWiQL1bcxXFI7YlnjejX/yqyb8oaYE1Da7DH/F61cwO5rkNHjFzFCKdvPSxVBY9NOZwmIuq76xgyax03u0VR@PDmuhQRioZYYiLAPLCiND5gyS@SRkJBLfoOapIPO1JZKOnU7tWLU4UGNcYRuoxSLmA3yYpzLfqbaQAO2xKt1dxf1FhzDeGRV5PZKKYxBXlWXQpoqbFXSlQcTt0SESQoqJm0ig9oYJw2CpzXePsbV6Aw4oSEtNAKSPf8ak0QuJ6YMPIa7yYQbRF0XE3ItIcpSQpPVihN46dFtVUs4wmVrc2Dkdlv@H8ES7eeOgnHBkZWZJVROAktM3WmTWJtX9GVQFC7oHSMojvWY5CKaPPvfq/B6xD6IOtWDx4MoTi9Kn/lTMDXaxdGstuOtanH1ceCJsBiQAJFfpvnfRNVT8izfpa3jo4hAokstGKJLOLx@iYlJoPN1TakdEbGnoNKPaUTbhZ@WvJeS/Ve20nl6Gn54DwCte3ArCtaR/Od8DfSKkP1av3xLcIa5g4oGzqTFK@e1QrviYX5wh3vkZQp1JIyrFWy8CAvq7jF@8QkqFllkmggMVaonk8RCMVv0vCcwVdIgIYgLxEjU1yXwJmwI/ITuNS1nlxIR5A3fUBASxIHqu1ex2ZZ@0IVkBnSJ0RICXkg4tN6p0Bxkp@BEFZe@S@AR2eobUnSTqUsm8s3CDlKgPscfTHXkEyPyOQrjwXO/hbNaW6kXtBJZXbBGHqxjY50VdyA7uhXdkUrS6k2j4Aqz5OfE@DozfJ9Npmk/dhVJ2FaegV1KQmjBw6JatTThfgR@1sgrvJI7ieBy/K1I3qtJsXjq3S5B0W2GSBTR5kj6ClIKllzyhTpnL96nhARaVZ6xLPTEmAZrvOKcctS2OUzlqSCn3iIHb83cCHxfxSB1TWXYo4GRhIe@pbKZEjBX62hjMCN3umREuOuTCYssxOwSESdk1elHqoz4a6FtaUSqnL2MLKwlyiZaD7hmZDC1ApDBJDjJAOKHPoRZQ1QKxtzTju/zrac@ozSYvHuh7FTEZLYz2gSAUE6lQozmsyFMc5bRasTWeuDlvbqjHXZtCXZ6jBbAUtXiPVX64KBtRysPFQf8yLuQk6yYnRvVZBpjUOgt5WOTIZHmbQGXMiZ7iGKXJJ9luzLYk7G0SkQQHa@OkEL0nXAZzCK0/JvsnhTI7jCEyaIvqBa6BuJsI@UPtBW8M@dUmON941JFQueI1BhytwJ6coCJ9YOiyUZ2IjCsMjMYlBu5CqkP/q1@9hujF7y/7kS1lEY@x7FDRXngyLKEQ0JPl7buBcCzlDo1tH@AKfVo51WOlgr5J3Av9gri7Ko4upIV@fkvpg5pyV/ggQcUK4eeSjGW@YRcwPC95xOULFL3QfcrYbd6aOsEkZo3suKq1I50ITSuoBIxLmS42jIlopFx6AZgz2JwYTOsMNNsmYDpGjAPVXygaQe0B/T4e7QkXsxCm/ALqdDcr9qdPbZdYb@RS0b2Vg6GCv4HBbOGNQKd@e0DClHg5HzyjrcUkdFw5q9dlUZyl4sJKvw5DJ1LenLAanM5hNi8v0lWAR0rfW43nhwGmcMCc6E5VWauupUxatBTz9RVgBqkUjKa7IG0n0ALVGt9f1ys4JE7a9aLOATyUE7UmZYpOVrvkLmi5JNVeJro1pUhacWwm39dWOUjR0FYnUapyntHvMNB0TmoRxNGrUIh01WyTLTgiC4GOLADHgx@j5cwaNLx5Hiez85gV0cRXHBnXJHT2QiRMm0KmxRtUvp257xJhRyoRkBCQIHKweHQ@/YQS20dVAYkUndxs7HIaWzRAlai@onddQRgqAZURlO@SbJc5CvE@@Q5R7RnEP@T3YieCYpsRUNCmGATVPPhQFKEmr4nPADnecMuoXGc5h8mwKGFFd5FQ8KD@2bG1TM6qBog7r6iorGM4z9Bi2t4FoK@EMoWHRYSpRFQEJ5U0ReBDeqA1LPVaPJZ8ghFvZ0XGHsZ2Pb/WVXKrUsMTbjnWDAGs2t7B6bKDHuuVxyNH3Y0MmoaMg6L@bhA3uOaKhJjmkuvhEghGoZuyu6wn9gSJpmuG@YYIEY2PjlbDZh0dyoMbDUtCDVg897fDCjUDgDap86DUa480PYS6t0qxCK@fGXw9UEk0kKLAmI@n8vMeJZq4PNRZB@9bdrWBBVBgJAr1RrLpmhzTtjJMcFcUg89jyiWDseOrS205A9nmHOYkF@yxjVZK4hlH2Q@4ElQvOURwEN9R/xftjaEiHnJ@smTe9l3TMcaVPZF0vKo34dheN18bVtvT9DdUDFt4JpsR4N4J2NIDR4QIres@KfB6kQsKEgpFgj2iEeVHoI31v2iUAZ2f9AcecJsVeg9UO6ZRcdoFgBk3/eCv80o1WIqfOcH@kEGRlIe4Ngmp7zXAl0TVVOjlBqP2AAZ9AvmNdSzZGjP3hFm9pnoGezLld@phsCGbvDCGAKTL4SkuvIDUBn2sOjQN2@ixD2OGX1GitHzbMGOC8U1fcdJ6iBWMc9OgYllSbh8@XKtTyESB@ko@VpwlN2amHlUwuFLc2UqsCqqR4rEt0zuE6mbXJ5S1sBIfhJlaMt@yIceJFG03Bx0cr7tkILNJ2o3IkgOmWqG9T/f9pChDAYEBbiQsDlFDkHz7Mh6c2i5LDFpXd4u6esq5sWcDTxL4jzGf0IJncSAvDLILkwY0A8t6RgWNGDb71a0cVTOCo5Pne2OcFTng3KSwZSb1bdaxplE4gwATQCn1JakiqGwcNT7J7TI0DdYP0KVIoYYZ7SzIRKPLcQovh2eRRtmSbCsBg3EqDOoQhKYCfEmpQkAFufiemuWHOPEKNGu@ZwAO4uteoN3q@xCs3QWa3QmPTCGJUlaSwHO68KAFJKjL99TailYSm3md3GqV8QjUqvdwBcgJjYTEQYfGNlzh8moEmHFlSwoPBKNQPy2jxvvblDkUaV4ADafx1oJXgDyxnZu6eTeOaPgCgVP33Qa0FutdsMNVNBmFw48vH7qwDehGFHo8q0XaOqsQbVswFIUIwAAOq5eZWwCN5Do/IojTUI4KmJbLdiKCmfoe1r6VAKE9Fz2sscsSQazZANIx68lHvDufQTpLJQPZCAEkP56G7ypFybbAb1v6ljgOHPxnL9YVPK@mEiWUcEkPlrIkWmScCKFBJZD1CsCtawDxVQi3D4Ky@ImakSRwKATHJk5JRqGI84V3BrJ8GCr3i6qjq5UQyxqyn0o7bkegdYS4f1RRPmB6DPXZvC6IIJaP0CJVIyIpsgQ6MJbpTUdI9AJgqrESnHmptU@4gyluQYkIG57NSOGrEniUZEQgKrVmtJOZE6IjiIt6/zQ717sWjIxgXZFDPVJY7LYGLipuZ4xFsWn0hOOqILEcZKfiCgCm9d009EtqGuQq@thnOg8S1AX@TjkDrfVSSU2BKHf5RZ/Xh3KabjEYSlCFUJE8AR@UKIfAQlaIvh6ocgpH0SQg3GCqiXlO9FWwQocEqGHKUQ9EPn3SsDucgBzYvlrg0ATKV1x/MNIh3BeeoWs06uJMESJNYAT2HYK7sSy4ZbPai5Ob2PWKLh6Q2khRGvCW6K0o/R0W5Jr0cOHHx9tYGidurD3EonIWTXF8nEU6qiT2Mza1YmbqMCtgiuNIB8HQBw4FihGAwBtwf4M8Vn@qG4yGNbUTe4nJaWKjqZxOR/kflfNbgjpMOFltpHNdwnApiXig@An8HAwXTUTdvl4TSYnNB509OvAspXi2MLPXhVmMQIm6QO5j5DqA5iD1nar55FQbNX0x2vO18kN7UwC07gXoigibB2vOUq1P@OP4pztS4McYdQU@Z66tRswT@hAho1tE05I1dE32zphqLdnrh2zs4wYlRh6ckWsFmYOIyHREnGZD7Q3KlkpjnMdjw4aTJV9U4EgXmaOxLQZUnj6GV0dA5qDVcmtgpNz41Nw/oZKzIWDFGiDvTDik1tlGPWUT5RSqfAuoVzlJHqXuMB3kLOqkTwnVcaqd3b/9/)

[Generator used](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7RRMJ5rNDf/)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 32148 bytes

```
import zlib, base64
exec(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode('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')))
```

**Explanation:** All that nonsense inside the `exec()` statement is actually the compressed version of `print('methionyl...'`

As per the OP's instructions, the hash of the output is `ec73f8229f7f8f2e542c316a41cbfff4`

This program uses the inbuilt Python modules `zlib` and `base64`

Comment: You coukd at least post the code without the data here.

Comment: @Titus I edited it in.

Comment: Is it really shorter to put the `print('` and `')` inside the compressed string and call `exec` rather than just to call `print` and only compress the string of interest?

Comment: pastebin link is now dead

Comment: ... and this isn't a valid answer anymore given it has no working code link and should be deleted.

Comment: @pppery I can verify that this once worked since I am pretty sure I tested the code back in 2017. In any case, I generated what should be the original code (same byte count, same output hash, goes `'eJzN...zYN'`). Thanks for bringing this to my attention.