# Print the Previous Answer!

Tags: answer-chaining

This is an [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge in which each answer builds on the previous answer. Taking no input, you are to output the most recent submission to this thread.

I would HIGHLY suggest [sorting by oldest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161757/print-the-previous-answer?answertab=oldest) and skipping to the last page to find the most recent answer.

## Scoring

The winner will be chosen based on a point system.

Every valid submission from each user is scored 1 point.

But here is the Fun part:

***If your submission is shorter (in bytes) than the previous answer (your output), your submissions score is multiplied by the difference in bytes.***

This being said, your answer does not have to be shorter than the previous one.

The winner is the user with the highest total point count and will be chosen after 2 weeks of inactivity on this thread.

## Rules

- Each new answer must be in an **UNIQUE** language, check the list below before posting an answer.
- You must wait at least 1 hour before submitting a new answer if you have just posted.
- You may NOT submit two answers in a row, you must wait for **TWO** more submissions before posting a new answer.
- of course, [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed
- Different versions of languages, e.g. Python 1, Python 2, and Python 3 are considered Different Languages.
- Output to stdout or your language's standard for outputting text
- Your code must not produce any errors
- Check to make sure that no one submitted an answer in the time that you were writing your own, and if so, please adjust and resubmit your code.
- **Please make sure that your answer is valid**
- Your output will be the previous answer and ONLY the previous answer. Whitespace and newlines are permitted provided that the output still runs as intended in the previous language.
- Please check your output to ensure that it runs correctly.

## Notes

- I'd like to encourage the use of esoteric languages to keep things interesting
- I'd also like to encourage the addition of [TIO](https://tio.run/#) links to make for easier testing and validation.

## Commencement

I will start off this challenge by posting a very simple Python 1 script:

```
print 1
```

The next submission should print this code EXACTLY.

## Formatting

Please format your post like this:

```
Answer Number - (language)

    [code]
    (preferably a TIO link)

[Submission Score]
[notes, explanations, whatever you want]
```

### Used Languages:

```js
$.ajax({type:"GET",url:"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/161757/answers?site=codegolf&filter=withbody&sort=creation&order=asc",success:function(data){for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++){var temp=document.createElement('p');temp.innerHTML = data.items[i].body.split("\n")[0];$('#list').append('<li><a href="/a/' + data.items[i].answer_id + '">' + temp.innerText || temp.textContent + '</a>');}}})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><base href="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com"><ul id="list"></ul>
```

*And a special Thank you to all of the other users  who have posted [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) questions, you have made writing this question a breeze.*

Comment: I'm not sure I get the scoring method. Isn't there any incentive for each answer to be golfed, obfuscate or whatever? Won't the answer chain essentially reduce to a lot of `print(...)`answers, with `print` replaced by `disp`, `fprintf` etc according to the chosen language?

Comment: There should be some sort of ending criteria apart from... running out of programming languages?

Comment: @JoKing I was thinking that this would encourage users to use languages that they aren't familiar with to continue the chain, and that perhaps they might stumble upon one that they really like, as I often do. But, if you have any suggestions on how to improve the scoring criterion, I'd be very excited to improve my challenge.

Comment: @LuisMendo I actually initially had the idea of encouraging obscure submissions, but didn’t know how to go about writing a question for that, What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: I suggest you get points per answer, where you get meh points for increasing the byte count, but lots of points for reducing the byte count. Or maybe restricting character usage based on the bytes in the previous answer?

Comment: Maybe something like "the score will be the smallest code length among all answers submitted by each participant". I'm not totally sure, as this is something that needs to be thought carefully. The [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) would have been very useful for this

Comment: [Nathaniel has a challenge almost identical to this one in the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/16058#16058), while the bytecount limit (and not the language limit) make it (IMO) more interesting. `/* Clearly not a dupe */`

Comment: To prevent a mass number of edits, I'd recommend having a code snippet that can scrape the answers and output a list of languages used. Otherwise most of the question will eventually be the languages used.

Comment: Is a DNS reliant WebRequest-Anwser valid? Looks like TIO cant resolve codegolf.stackexchange.com (atleast for C# WebRequest)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've changed the list to a JS snippet. It's very basic, because I suck at JS, so perhaps someone could make it prettier and add a search/sort option for the languages. But it does the trick for now. It's sorted by creation date.

Comment: @Hyarus Because of the standard norms of code golf, I feel like I’m obligated to say no, but honestly unique answers always peak my interest, so I’d say go for it! To keep the hard core competitors happy, I guess I have to say that a answer that reads the page WONT be counted to your score, but with that said, I’m super interested in seeing your solution ;)

Comment: @X1M4L [TIO](https://tio.run/##VZBNTwIxEIbP21/R7KmNbDccgOi6JIYYw0ExYMJBPZTusDTuttgOH4bw25euEIPHTp637zOjfKK8akikKuk9fXW2dLIm0YFEkUeJWtGt1QV9ltowj06b8v2TSld6HogDmf14hFo8KNTWUEnzhvF8eNhKRzE3sKMXYDwRM3Qg6ynIAhy7jF8AxRwWU/jegEcxCgQCi1eIa3@XpsoWUNpqKYKK@oK9WklTglC2Tn8DodOn3X530BvEXDwBTsGvwwzYv9e5mXEu2vY3@2gKxrPWUecoxqaA/WTJYl3kH7E0fgcuaT@97cVnSl1T963UMO5oftPPLmuMQoutQMydDvooZpvF@VZMda6j6V82UZxnxyYjMpiESx4JIdGxOQE). I think it is better suited here as a calification for "WebRequest-Answer" (Sadly it doesnt resolve). And this way we dont disrupt the nice chain of valid answers.

Comment: @Hyarus That's a standard loophole, which are specifically disallowed.

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this challenge because I think it generates many boring answers that do not have much effort put into them.

Comment: It might be helpful to change the snippet to https…

Comment: [Is a trailing newline allowed](https://tio.run/##XZBLb4MwDMfv@RReNwk4tHmxPA6b9pQ2qbcdEQegrK2mAgp0rVT62VkIpevmRI7/juOflTSpV11XmXXRfILnTqAe3ENlyiVF44XvLOhXcDiet1X@hQX/K6Io9oP4V0RxPOYi6/pEH/R6ZLIzMxSMh5yJUNJbQTUNBZWSSKEll1xprblS9mSEhKHUTEqqQkUEYVpqRal9KZUQ1hFFQLSv5jDxgyg@HCcPm5HGEcJl1eDUJOtilWRf@KmP3mwE08dhIFtabhuGsk01/IqT0LaQZ6vylLq6G4rQpixKcD3rJtnjD@vmSbGcPc/fcbou8Euebpfubpbvc5huhzkGCD9DmJN/IOwEsTPvMphmJ/JF9dCphTpfgHez8BC6hixpANfmG@9MUlW5qR27634A)? What about trailing `\r` or `¶` or equivalent in language's codepage?

Comment: It happens that the 5th answer by StewieGriffin is wrong.

Comment: ...because the code posted in the 4th answer is wrong @user202729.

Comment: @StewieGriffin They do post a Base64. Conclusion: [blame-se].

Comment: It shows the question unintendly makes kinds of strange happen,

Comment: I posted my Perl answer just before the C# answer (seconds in it), but it looks like the chain continued from the C# answer. Should I just remove mine to avoid any further confusion?

Comment: Time to post a 10^345915195 byte Lenguage answer and kill this challenge...

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn couldn’t someone just then post something like `print '\n'*10**345915195`? I guess that would just effectively make them the winner.

Comment: @dylnan you underestimate how many bytes itd take to outout 53000 bytes in lenguege.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I was just using the number you used

Comment: Maybe constrain the byte size to less than 10^10?

Comment: if any of these answers end up being `1`, this is a chain quine

Answer (score 8):

## 2. [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 98 bytes

```
(((((()()()){}){}){}){}())(((((((((((()()()()){}){}){})[[]()]){}){})[[][]])[[]()])[()][][])[()()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAww0QVCzuhaOgDwNJKCJriI6OlZDMxbBiY6NhYlFAwmQAIgB4v///1/XEQA)

Starting off <s>strong</s> long. Outputs [`print 1`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161759/76162).

Comment: I immediately regret this

Comment: It kinda made every single answer after this rather boring, yes..

Comment: To be fair, the question doesn’t really encourage clever answers

Answer (score 8):

## 20. [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 24143 bytes

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVxbjhzHEfyOPkVczTAEWH8GbMDHp6nZ7e6MR9ZKIihxZjlTXZXPiMj637/@/O8f//n3P/75x69fJMDf/4DX5/ff/wLX59W/ft0vfv6Lz4/i8@t@435nfsbn1@cPn095Xv76B9@f9/k44H7v/mLi@6s/P3w963t@8Osvzo@8l/f@7c/vxLPq@zn@Wtj9kWO1uL@asiS@W/B5wu9VPc/19c78qXsZ@F6a/N3xgOMr702FPP7XT9MO4vutz9vPIr@/7l7/@FC@y333LD/@XfI4i/tn34e5xiE9H3bv4/chfa93nMW7I3Ea9wrfRY4zGcuVs7pt7t2Dselg30N5QbZ9buW0A6ZBySm7Rd/PNM7XN/P5aWKa3ti953/FDd4XxIw/r/GHFb7OAHXl76elW8u9j288AGmWStlUPrb1nsTzxbdRPJb6tSO2PvGV21Me9xoGgxEH4ssek0Du@HCD98PG4w8z@N6K1@5LhJKoA2JbSRzNNN/pEN9f8KwA5tcj/OASL/o@rDvceeB5NlhekNg44oSEej34sGHOx49ojPEEzHXx2ajxyJeEg7AUX@l7Nk@ckUQFytJG/C0frDmg5qt3DeLAHOny9QKPEGJSw1jeP7yuZ9FSTN1D2nTHez1PEI4HpEdlMX6ghLY3tmIe1rtXkotmAHxDthcPHiKeHXxrkJ7F7kMSb@IbJ97nQ5QD70bPNbpVzsrA4l2c3e1Muj2R@uGhBziezR3/ZqAeVQs8OaDZJkaVFnF7xi6PUmFKEqQx8lbk7HfZsgfjCR7X83WhB3@Lvi3gva/XqDvSxUgpYeQzTgx36PHlMcLx6VoKn9J6KwOsdnaHyMMeHzviFUrgNWcsDxxRF1mvwCPOEwqGN7@Lgp/3U7G9O4oMNOZJ70@P8PjarFSs9hDDAOhJdX5V2RgvQQEpi2bxj7S4CHf@FVh7goiGrxlKbcFz8JAoYa2Cl9trv9GqRDIKFl7aFL1pDhaYoB@Pfkpb@q4RXWzMN3J66bbHt2Ghx4zeMmC44Ujr8uSSCHAttikl1CiH3v9CQ7CW3sPWRl/7xijxmS2Sa6fCnv/VWiiFzjgf/BBBp2OtTcKTtkqys6OZWTL7ba33pJvhFt4iN1FwDB79cPysHsICfkgD3n2lNgcgWpM3G0XJJ1b4OgTj0et1afQyiYu1vLl/POOoTXsT8fVKLxC9BjV4RiocS5BWOsyc@C5ymqg0zxNbmNAKS9XbvRmzKZ5tzqzkir@8VsoKvK0e4Y1GdTK2zKQxINs5iptLgZiwIBzXAJEo2GMcGVhQqkdpCEaVDWwYQrwr@BfUNEfPXpsuaegC0MRqq9O4BC7QP0xnme5gWJcnIS6YCwcQJ7DP2B8HFBU5mk3euzKF2qLbI2ntPHYrepZT2vEAeOdmXIHYOeD8nEpf8TxRePKdKLKVfxUEruFZytu/VQU5mnKfSaDQUTe9YCzJWsXI0c7qWrAknspg7RPlpBVll1ze2hDPMVRMcKB3XppqvdKwx6wrCAOINKtFm51BnQs4HFwAJsg5rIa9IM3OfEO7PU8WA9QY5BAmF7@qlnyftbd2rLUP2t8LQgAr5/CYCXAFwg9F@L3vXApCP3FLUi2fuNe9KTvKlka@WFyWDYwCRcC7FZx63/PKNrKYUHGkxiwG3uJl4QqeTzgwy2vlRhyM0apfMus8L@kiWpp9ahRETHiyMzeUnyu2/lodg5YogGd2Scg6wWDsTr3spEoNNWOdaJnhXRIXfpJMlga1m5bKaSmJuJCrFFCEgdoNak7AM64YgPmfhjLpSQOKoCJmFZ5tBtoLAQGrZmMIA@iM8ZwQJjSKRgunlTMSLuKx@vBWBisxcGmDFkF4NpjY2ItZ2akPXVSIrtA6Iy/UqBtJWeFC8zTWOtzgUMzqcelCUCHmjQkLdMOSF43lN4jUaKpu0Frdrx0eEkoY7hhWaxATAiGENg57q5iFNU7FwJLpnOfD4uRmBSWChtsbgbCTzVz5Aqlx9Miic8y6UaqNUAqczz7sBWudksRDUu7opWU4VBR5pdwa9oHGLBhGTkkRWJrvY7TjIM61RADWfdIWPdNIJI2E3gUw60IKaENfEoq20KHEgRKegdoE4Y@A27l3W8@yLwrWcu4A3KHpXarD0jzUKSyl6FxSFH9bZwcFn5Jlkd5nSZYm70FWZRL1ZYsLf1NIMnITI2SvKV12Afpn/VCQH42uwXBIODWLVO0EDLUr2ofGCMsGhRKJR2GfIm1erzeECJXiWlVVgciqSsPFI2TWOzP5t/4/a8IOKbK3DcZC5YdrJ0vOtL1QGVo1Lewzapux0iauw0OILqIdmO07iSRcZwZ3@mrT3b102EYcmYinhTIngA3i6jxCMZYmNjQJlvkJHLw@qRkauqLuVEhubpRW1WvNBW3oT9V5ja0xlRP2Qq/AaxSiqVDVQYCoBgoO/WYFtFQyU7lyAsKycr0W5QpX@sUiIbQXzkdpcavJM1kgVMUBNVQbkLMw4Um5g1WOXQD8RYyEWFIpjASptii3lzWuzKbKtlpTHoLBVpQ1NCmIDldGmSNJ5tJaKsUxnm@al/Z2BIskcQZtlXGJyp@ig90o2El7L4hiQG9HZRuOcA7hgAaLbkxasBW9l6zEIl5Ye@DiT4vUFieuFILAByNArKpnUUpZnPD8zsuaQJMdJU@SylmF4xsTIZU@FlUcmUHSIcl9JsTeA9jr3vJC0VVZ3eoK3RFgsqW5StGKVMFBKjSsoxoNcnfJseVsTMVriiiBBnUqz3k5mu7CpRzIEHg@o1WTKfFHCbtjhqHzTlruCOBXMYArnmqi46Ud/mWhL0/1MqhwzyZdSqDGj45Nb@kTo1TpivIiFNxoU5keyePoSKmUI/hBNpu8MTSqcg04KzoqXXhWBHVgRoVZjiQkztdCCXhUKHtqQVdUokCYOTEEDwMntE@m84YeCyeue2HUppB2cz6nH4nkKbOBsnGXlIzvZCFx0PDatrJFwcNME1gJxBzvgGXVaA@wY8Azc7NxTEfqZ90JqYlULNZqSBQxemO44Lbgug@qILUKD1TvqEHiSj00Cg0kPfVC4GtZpUDGqVTYBNfHXk1LFHXK2s@HuNPmX7yDpFOo0BhbRm2LemSiJYXcR/bGldwDtokYZwkmwsJ9rVIEXlt0sAraxq9a7771PNuoLpZ@1SdbgCOcC6aeNLGBNptbMAGVls10mR2ZAZ1TT7gvOKYmBtgmlDijCMahh/BI7NCeYUeIUT0UgfzWjdOI6sF4nqe3UIQF0bl0GTjZ2Jg2s6ZjezuxzJNOFNmWFy1ELyywWic0zSYpHow@C77SudFnfxbhM6Vxx6nVbRjyYYsSPWYQdDKWYKBRlWezC93WvplQhf9VYo7DMBKEfR7ptcuDLtamSbjQMxvloqahKftvjrkKY8llvn6fFVR1G85YLWxkAg1z8qoyhpA6@365hECmE4ieMWUwLWbkFvKBRTC7QIiqkYG7cZMOcrkmY1SAy@AN95HG4f9574Qm2CYLSsD@R62Wa1d7d6F6UJ2@c7IoFK5E3g6ydHRtLhhl7k22CS73NlXKD0oOg1B8HpCN5t5ur/CC2tVDyyADjo1EBLNq7OGtK34TnXDyHIrddbNCvdhE0ctAvBYKB1FAR2zcSFpGonbcawO6HdyoAaDWq01bYBzpXtfobqb5CbS9YYdN41TnLdpQOepkCg6DT/Flke1hc0S7Phh9nApA042c0OfMLk4vn8dIjT4LyhExoaE3mxSED9kAtBljLmLlmHA/TZZVqAubJFc0TKXHsQtxys0voeur6EChZ7kPmgI9t2kTv08mSqpB4XZDlrYOXZ0xnJDx2Rf@LC4lN@EJSZwntX4YOww40nh8LGDFrlF1lqIiZ8Gxcq3EUnXDnfFW@K@rG1YUPK5DQpOJYXRROnGLXX5ppTAO4qe1q9wmVFUdtF@gVYcqWcMF@g0NPrOHI6Nsc2rt4gESR01CW/PSjbi2Dkh10qbojhuxllnUfuMZrLlIolx0HgcRCvaJD0HoxOu43w1QRGxXGQNmmaY6kni1wVyNtQzj4jy4ewhpFu1dhBaDpXHBm49ZdblyzLHa1Uw8t4@sY7utI1hH@0ufuCsxVlHdQUhYJkaE4s@ZIiNkSsm2GDBOuRM1Fmi1aWLtSjbsAgIsOhO70SWmpDqNand4lC4XK06ZXea8d2R0xftNmHqpxUE@uvFQK1gjsH5IQZJv92Ga0RvQpmooXKfoK/MazryAcsMiXU3pvqAToT2CsKo7tOeVO8AWa2G/n8qAnH7pXbR@KNcBWtV@ntFem5dQjrQxdx20TFBO9EuH@yscbDUd7DadrUv2yxXsctpUkdrljjzH@DeYuPGGdbWbYa0WrwzEwq1SIhzK2A200pRbMNfryfJDY39MGr/QPfj78xBtWrKOR9ktOyd5yZrBnwe4ugjKhoEOIn4vsfSeHI2b5f5RlitngJPM1rEJxUn7PWz9OgKQ7ebEFVBVJn3eKmq6MgSTzX77n3XdGmJIHsajewWkKD5xkj61a8LitqgqfI5YE5fz6nBMRxIOc0rWhKzJcpM/r4IlkVEcWi76zRwn7LddIYJTVdpmelkvMem6ObvKAZTbTQ7DI2ycvc11bCxr3B7l1bVdBll7dav81IUqRm/QsrLmdEbf7lieYgr6MGMBTlyukXKMZy@u4dq///f@uuv3O79@/R8)

Generated with [this Java program](https://tio.run/##bVdrU1PJFv0@v@IYkYcICo7IS3mpoOgootcHAYkQIPI0CaCDWAkK0QRUoIrAzBUSyKOYASZBgXNOIFR1n3Sd5F80f8RZfXDmTt17qxRIuk/33muvvdY@zywjloJnnb3fvnX0WRwO6ZbFNjD2gyQNDT/ts3VIDqfFiV8jg7ZOqR9Luc1Ou22gu6VVsuSJbZJ0/IU0ZB/stlv67w3WDQ6MWO1O6ZI0YB39vlo73NVltedaWs615hXarVh3WHPz8k2min8e0XH8pLUTz/611DVoz@3osdilDqn8f@4odA7WYa3Gbre8zM37Ho8k2Qackg1ndBQUnTtX8f3L73c8tQ1Y7C@xeH3Aae222nFErfHV8XqurfJcVYGt3Jb313P/CSofUUmSKd/YYzI7TeUmyfT3PhGouLiz/PiKwm6rs/al0@r4R2D/dVrnpUs/lkpVONWE5MSJfx02/n8vNw983zAufhwj99LhtPYXDg47C4cQvzP37yfysV2SxH/J7DQ7xU/xUfwUXxyv4fPAcQrjP4x/@/YNAHdYHY5Ch7NTHDlqtzmtkunI9W/Ny9xkm8tvLtYOcSXAvOOp@ZtcWWvqZp@5/OVyaq6Oqx@Gj9zJjK@4mavzqQQJHbn3tFgXVxYzPq5O5XM1cEvz8cQ0Vz/ebmEbz@kiNnL57chVHKF5tXiNdsiV30e44mJhNk/jNKbFb5JEBQK4xuUJ6qGfuPK2OFePjFIPT8zwRPheysVmc8gq2eCJEJfXtGARVzwkaOl@ceQ@4Oq7K2e48tuRe/c2@YIjuJJMbx9NbDh62LscophN17JsY805R26lki4ThUaoP4v60/tn22iUq0E9SiPs3SPNW9WJENl8JpBXT1aP3DsnyVZBC1c2W@gyUpK/cOVXs9leksWWGrhyiLho/BW@prO55TyxQ9b70vFKrkzokdQ@EtbDZVqcfMnvIqGus/XApZGsDb1mbq78Qta4PF2bmXiKqLmydO8q2SmiEW3hFFsiq5eBZWqezqYjmYDmB5J0uUCPnuaqIg1wJViP/LnqLUFcjspmLXDebCKrXJns4vIkl73PUR3Aq0dZqAbAWyvYZmYCSRYBEffBiLZADtPxI/dXrs5xxY0tHlyXK@JI7HB5pZdtnhvj8h6Xw@O5ABaX/YzbShlgnzxzFqCm/chN7FcVcnCBJ3xajCt@8S8RlnjiawUIQWNkC9Wgn0j4FIgkHtnOe8UVxLlIpxxHbpW59QiXfeV3bfiQx2XALdNFutfOlQ2uylyZqkL0hQJjv@bl8kw68FyPaoGU686YAYAHOaS3wQKRi5JsRQCZCS1mZB98wFVfUdovEn9/mybTKAMQwof2LiTDlTd0ls0Xss855AAR49HUHMqNUJNsQ99DTuPgoBx@8qOgHxBKhA1iIHugjmV8nWeEoILybbfppx6sH8W3NF8BUZAw9bA5wZfEzB3AVIgVRAnOrOGGcT1M1mvZBvB5STacoCubJ6HrdAoNMzSGR7SFbFyEZ1D6fhJqFtQ6JJF24KH5XosE5T2p6wJdRPBqAAHpURGS8guSZrNFZPVRD13uFzErAXzVjRBxyYlbbWyJelIJsfsrLjeC2knHLz7teSoSn6XLdPYGavscxcLh62RXJKskLwsajZ7h8m41OdS8p0mov6CSbNEkqhwR1ypvtRiIKof78WTjNaMTk3l6lOykEnTlyL2vh8D6RLiF7GRXC23wPqlnqOkqTQq0gmzRbKafnKPFdnSoIJI8jTDqUy6wxSbQlHvS@4i1LA9aApYqgTYnuESnsJ1GUSPva8FY9T1RALO2cAlnolUhFeeaWxuAor0elJ/YuDWC58FB9cP99sJCckhnx8G6JuauY59pHKmjQ3C6C80Xwz1YQw3HBZCJmXQcaY2CsYOjQp6CVgeJCd1JzaNsuAmkR1zVZJ1O6dHqMSzd1PxEGbKMlgMMskb9GV8KnFghOygWGjbho3sPSVDwsUDfa0E7dpBQ5Wk9WvkoHf/5Gki@rG8ZfO7ITQcASRkSpCDqs2ZR14S38g5a5TGK22CUaZVscWVBpCdPM3c9lR8LZMPUU8Bl9O7K82sItAuZ1HXdSSWgUohnHoqA0xba0vtQIXAFvwWToE44ZtdsgrSA8ckmXH0lEwDdgQkMYZHE2muFlKPmD0uRuiRaVp4BGS5DAN1ITw63Xrbjq8ambvRyycVnZA21NiSmgmzgYQYp3/kJH3OoB2tBwYuZHgLS@vUtNvsotY8o1XmyjlAvUr9x@q9jQ/ntJaUgZmIa1BN96HtUgiRK0CTTQ9CO5CVyoEfuIl4WFkmoH@5cqdUWus/D1MCp4j4SBEVK0ZQDJ2AqF7QYmLSUCXRrXhrLb4B47goZVeduYBuNDaHWOOoz2aFTbJNBbn5jS@Aa9Q@hMDmjBUaXQdU2a7E/W7ieHC5zoChavMdszj51im0jUSiIPGOIyFsSNNTNY88E2OaJLLjgZj8A1RaK4HXyiiCg6h0SrILqTHdQwIqCvGXvtAXmQcumXLfJbiZgBUwUsMszgqXK72SV@vHXkRuVDcB9lEPIGAR6nawxTyP@uk73SNiK/STMgP3YI2HKymQeik2j5IAcFo9UIzVlqZL6kafq62SzDWYTPApypP8BUBj2e7Sg6LSEV0wH8w7B7BgJP6Hg/qIQQ2WyBGn2Xu8FCVA@eaXzLtlgm5AAuldFwi@Y8JxbNSjbBYh4vnjEcGuEPpiOXOnTt4oJdBaZD4LcRXSxG0Wsa3qW8YF1rqrxfLJFvozRFWzIHu8Fwicrc0EbB1FuZFey7dScHn4NmjihAIDvKwv3lCCVs1IHDBA0fYbINX9zo5MutxpuKbxL/ahHYBTKJIM4wDAwxShCHt37/YblYwyiSaCprL1AJwls35AtzU@Xm7EL8xIaxF@DEoxRDzz6w4O6lOs@Mk8HyEEJWLQDi/QKWilJHJzxdRVk4If6FllvxALgi5XRKHBRPzYbWEy0kAjZPfWk766Gx3a0wMmq1n8NwNhbG@xIG1mUC6U7HL0NSpc9TvvTgWFoRWqOua@i/waOxR2TFYq52ttaTKPDP8EolKXngN6hh0Qt12pxUud1ZFLFZgGs5i8GaoKoH7UgXTmFS5x34SA7141BYQogfpSatBgucEPJVaiuHmooxZMgWITGbsKI1XfZeqgXJFb8KNo2ewdIhM64tOBtZNXLlhzCegXqkBffQ7bU1VSFjSdqsRGkAhKK@CsxnZnoY@E@YVPIVsGYoM5VoxLFJALEpgUNXZmAwAreLE@KgW8VXSWHSzKBLIiZ2YxankUHiIFHLa642p2D2tUhwVYh4m@ofAEntpBVm5CjxHQR2UbAyzU0Sj3pbeYdaaDJvswECp0ICzsB1@G@1HOXbWMoDmJyCEFSJ0FibwFbtFbpW3qklrnF1BNNzUnGQOU2WmRVzD0h6kcPLmVp8bYWfHsOMq2@h9qgX76yRUwRH9DeDtH3x1NNfKsjE2gmStnxtKQF4FOfUq76Bw21qX2YhzzD3pFDYTfqeyvw0YKXT2cm0vuQ9lAF0rcY0znUUZ5@RQ5FiupcFTQy@dNpMbTJuyjbb8JXEtrCCNiuhwSU8lqNqBjQpMsPMgHqv6fF2sCj9D6aTQ7nXDxNDkQ23vxH4LZwgA09XH9emNmM0SVrYqgXXvMFrwFKECxT5WdIQWCdf74SrOxncyWodxuMWDi7Rwyg8m5bqdGqvnTEQMLfcKuxkYjC3RgBH5VV7Kafsuns8FVEQ1bPp/Zz9AiYIvuQwaiYkzA3LpvN/WUYoOSZx8xDI3jabIKJLN7HVJh8IIxLfiV4s5Zy2QxVHBZ2oPpojM1mZSZuCJUNM5howA5IvNUGUDM16A1Ao87R5Ry6rIdEe50wxscpYD0kjOoP@qnyyQVI1cvHRkbvR/F@EdECmg/h7p1JB8Bida4cR8tevFipHsvD5/reCVRbKhWiKQalQfEetS9eniDkSWGAGyj0BkxOXskym9MRQRWZBNN@TP8bR64lvCdlIYt6QN9uuOj9O8bA49L3aCSVOMnC0J5tvO18fSLesTx0j84a9gfxgtuBucIYvUbTb7I5nPorRvNgp7aAyW8alo@5UMUgs9IFZxUr0Kd5MWmizvL2dep5yBZRg@0bQB@vYHq0rI5OPR27Yifr7U3YkY0wB9txk@siPiG7NATdl0U9WvwW@g3D@CGbr4XnIOalbrzlTJyAMaYSeQCjhHn1yAuIycBFkjD9CQ) based on [this Whitespace tip I wrote](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210).

Only three characters used. Byte-size may have been through the roof by now, but at least we're back to printable ASCII. ;p

Comment: +1... I really really hope the next in line answers using printable ASCII that don't rely on built in compression functions!

Comment: @StewieGriffin I hope so too, but I doubt it. There have been some attempts to make it ASCII again, but it doesn't take long for it to be back to non-ASCII. ASCII answers thus far: 1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 17, 20. Non-ASCII answers thus far: 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19.

Comment: As a huge fan of Whitespace, this is the most horrifically beautiful thing I’ve ever seen. Also quite possibly the longest code golf answer I’ve ever encountered.

Comment: @X1M4L "_Also quite possibly the longest code golf answer I’ve ever encountered._" Wait until someone posts a [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage) answer. ;p [Here is an 'extremely short' Lenguage answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/104262/52210) of 56623 bytes, but usually it's a bit higher: [example 1: 2293382937520069758100171520285996319 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131882/52210), [example 2: 4.54*10^761 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73729/52210), [example 3: 5.71728886*10^3431 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122068/52210), etc.

Comment: [Or this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68823/31516).''

Comment: Some men just like to watch the world burn huh?

Answer (score 7):

## 29. [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 1.15733 × 10<sup>1780573</sup> bytes

A string of [this many](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3q4gaxco2d5jigp/number.txt/file) `0`s.
<sub><sub>Hey, at least it's ASCII.</sub></sub>

Comment: Behold! *My secret weapon!*

Comment: Could you please put this in a paste site where I *don't* need to log in?

Comment: @Seggan 1: Oops, I don't think that website required a login when I posted this originally. 2: No, it's too big. Instead, I've uploaded a text file with it to MediaFire.

Answer (score 6):

## 3. - [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 92 bytes

```
4623432647156191461770769737389993883892004479277184806029798113267866678080 6|Er{"()[]{}"@m
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=4623432647156191461770769737389993883892004479277184806029798113267866678080+6%7CEr%7B%22%28%29[]%7B%7D%22%40m&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 5):

## 5. MATLAB, 331 bytes

Luckily, it is not specified that only free languages can be used. This works the same way in Octave. Used MATLAB here instead of Octave, since Octave offers more golfing options and is more forgiving when it comes to strange syntax, thus it can be used later more easily.

```matlab
disp([97,108,101,114,116,40,98,116,111,97,96,227,173,183,227,125,186,227,189,121,235,95,117,227,173,123,239,78,250,247,189,251,223,207,125,247,60,223,207,118,211,78,56,239,221,187,239,95,56,243,78,180,219,222,253,243,93,119,219,174,252,235,174,187,243,79,52,96,43,39,32,54,124,69,114,123,34,40,41,91,93,123,125,34,64,109,39,41,''])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVA7DkIxDDvOAylD8@knZ0EMCBiYQAJx/eKkSG@I5Dq2k@Z5/Vy@9zlvj/frcPJOXAaKidlQjayQj0TMTBB4IxHouhIPXVgq8J8fjjeTaCUHzX2XC@Tq1AdJLSS21FKhjlZZScG3slMMOUbDVVv6BfE8emKMCNY0@jxg4xAIUjVpx9ygUNwNtORqgTMjnE5g8S9gRKpQRVOMmq8zYBO1uIThApyRorkr6AZB8TCiu23n45w/) (Runs in Octave)

I'll bring it back to the realm of printable ASCII. It's horribly long, but I hope I'm making it a bit easier for the next one. Hopefully it won't just go back to a compressed string.

```matlab
disp([str2num(reshape('097108101114116040098116111097096227173183227125186227189121235095117227173123239078250247189251223207125247060223207118211078056239221187239095056243078180219222253243093119219174252235174187243079052096043039032054124069114123034040041091093123125034064109039041',3,[])'),'']')
```

Comment: Your code returns my code encoded by stackexchange, not the original code

Comment: It returns the one you posted in the answer (as far as I can tell). How should I guess that the code you posted was not the original code?

Comment: well I didn't know either ,,,

Comment: According to the base64 and octave, [your code is wrong](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43930054#43930054).

Comment: [This is the result of my code, compared to the code in the previous answer](https://tio.run/##zZCxCoJQGIX3nkJcrtJYhENCS6s9QIhaBBWVYrdCzGdoaJRqcJR0MBA0l/88mF3foukczrd8HC/ga/cwaFt3ySVdYow5u5XPlQV3HRsJvalEElElahMgtU7dFiI3UKGkBjVeuEUox12ecTc05HhQjdzSUBj0QYwnGhTmBTFl@CKlTOBiNrT7TBpdp34oK@rcDCN5smeqEOhtj96/qHj@5sAV8Y2uCyu1bX8), as it is shown in the post. How should I know that the code posted in the answer was not the actual code? There is a base64 string, but it doesn't say anywhere that they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

## 15. [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 1146 bytes

Shortened it 104 bytes :)

```matlab
k='#include <';m=~(1:10)+77;disp([k,'iostream>',10,k,'string>',10,'using namespace std::string_literals;',10,'int main(){std::cout<<"$><<\"Fb["+"泫Aѹ୽Ñ຃Á຃°ʂÑ຃Ñ຃Ñ຃Ñ൒±๳mBय़൘\0੝ЌࡢѬɳάΊ֬ୱҌݨٻ๺ӁणёĚҡ੝2Ś`ɪ¿࡯\0੯μݑלٶԋ๥ّࠜЂพѿࠠҏԢ΢ܚ؁g\0ࢆ̌ɿ׼މԌɕ؜ɸѼљ̌ંΌࡼμʇл๺ӟܜ̏ฤ֐วͯࠜעఢѢढ۲ԟ͢ਛϱࠣײРͱ̟֡ؠկഞԲܦՐНف؝ۢണڿటұฦԀచҢࢊ¯୲`ͯ‚XP੭ƈ඄Ќމ؋๤Ԡ\"ҰԢՒఢհढүଛտଟհ̠ڏचӂż൭Ѽख़Ӭࡸ׼զ".unpack("U*").map{|i|47882-i}*'' ''+")=+kCb)Fb["+"',[93+[148,0,0,0]'+reshape([~(1:154),'MMMLMMMLMMMMLMLMLMMMML',~(1:24)+77,'LMLMLMMMMMMLMLMMLLLMLLLMMLML',m,'MLMMMMMLMMMMMLMMMLLML',m,'MLMLMLLLLL',m,'LMLLMLLLMLMMMMLMMML$Q&\(()`&$/=YIZ=WQ/91Y25*Q&D$,,$&,-$$0%42838*9Y1[%WQ-Q%P2X.`/%XUY5X]W=(`,Y-1&('')+Q3<*`&0-0+`-@,,/X*$/aZAWA0A.Q$8*D*)Z1Y,Z]ZUWM2%,A0Q08.X*aZ%Y]XAW=%Q+T1L/SO:3/S7466.T]4E5&U[PE07PN_NF5%5C2$5S:E6C06:4.5^4#%@U:/96:&0T.E1%15I#=TR@`PK`)``0KO94;F:S0V6S8#/5:S:E.VNTKT(`=_935V.S.$HSaC#EBUGP7@=/M55%.DPT%S:6(T4O858U3&S'],[],4)'](:)','".unpack("U*").map{|i|481339-i}*'' ''+'')=+kCb)+++"puts "NkN'''])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJrTxtHFIaVv9BfYBmvZ9e7Xu/au74sdoTDpY1Yg13b@Iab3YCVWmCDsOmXpBdo1TapJSBSpYZAbJZLk9TIBkJkEldITlOJCFzb2FwSEs2n/g26YJrmSzWao/POPGeOZuYdGUiKX0ROT4dsoCUaHxgeH4worKA1ZvsKpTmawnCTqXUwmhhFQ0MEiI4kkmMRMXYZEDRFyAuyjMZvNCUYT8i5Ii7GIolRcSCiSCQHOa5JXBuOJiNj4nCitYlG40lFTIzGUezmOTUwMp60WpWqy1Zrv7LrekiJK//e@M1e3foIrv7@YgY@@/bFhBxK@VeTTfVh2LxbWoNbG6Xp2BW4nC5Nwc1f@in4aL6SggtSNbuzUc6W7xxk4epaLfX24fFzuPVsfwIuLVZn/pitLcig/uWssPO4tA0XcmeFuXLx7czh3PHT@k9wa/l4BmbmKpOw8KC6DTOZ2lRdKksns0cTN2RW@n43tbN9WHx3u57a@flobqdQLVbv7abg48my3L1YLr76oXLeMH0ytzsFC0sH07Dw615OPvNQgnmpKsEl6c16Pb0nwYf3/1qDmcXD9Upmb203fbBwlGnk4JMH9fWTlcZ0Zf544mj@jQSfLL7ehvl0bQ0WVurfwPxsTYLSnVIOrq4Le7nSpN8JH61@/eePl@DT7yqpd7eP5Fss1TP9ylq@LjXuyk0beblpLQez9xvbMJtu5Hczr6fg0uz@5MviJbi5Wi3C5Xv7WbhQOCw2VpTkeFz@zyFU6dUoMTImjt68Fb3FmMxmvTb6pQYABQC4ErPhQ@3XsebfASJkMeAhmjET1NkIA3wskvhcHI2goXNfsQxGAIfDwV9MOfAXCSDOCD1z5jwCvF9vIg6e58/nmQJETD6Ev9j8N/If7JyzfFPyjotS/j2pcqn7URQT1CqdLXA1aPO5dBY6oGc1LnWHiiBUakKrUlEIozcbzBpLgA4hPpfWhTj1flLQIX5vgPWHfTZUIAJaWo0CgOEug1UjqCkthQvaNoLQ@TUqnRi0@@yUnXSpzJoODRakA0QwHPT6HHqEsFMuykz6NWIQCYT9dp8NceEemte5ezmDzm1ijEbSE2Y6WbU35OykTM6eaz1dLMK261Wsm@s0tlNGjiHZz5gWpM3L6SxGTk15yE4aodmrLTbPp22Cs1vABIHq7rUwrV2cm@ozus0tOpaTq8m@Hk@3BxVs1ywGto90k6pP3GJ7S@cV78dOU5tN52BZhOxwehA3Z0Q9TK@ZNXsNajcIE6EwwWAgjHIYIMD/2MNMGwyW//whP07TIDiOK0fHkwmFsmeoBwAQxk5P/wE)

**It was time for some golfing!**

Some of what has been done:

- Stored `#include <` as a variable and used it twice
- Stored `m=~(1:10)+77` as a variable (`MMMMMMMMMM`), and used it three times
- Ripped apart the following combined Unicode characters, and created them manually.

```matlab
''
```

The table below show the first 12 unicode characters from the string above, with the four code points that are used to create them below.

```matlab
                                                     
241   241   241   241   241   241   241   241   241   241   241   241
170   170   170   169   170   170   170   169   170   170   170   170
129   174   131   185   133   133   134   189   131   129   140   154
172   151   144   140   176   148   145   147   147   139   177   186
```

As you can see, all start with `241`, then there's either `170` or `169`, while the two last numbers vary a lot. The shortest way to create long numeric arrays in Octave is to create a string, then convert the code points to numbers. If we subtract `93` from the bottom three rows, we get code points that are within the printable ASCII-range. (`93` was chosen to avoid `'` as much as possible, since they require an extra escape character.

There's quite a bit more to it than that, for instance some reshaping, transposing concatenation etc, but the explanation gets long and messy if I keep going, so I'll just leave it like this.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, since it was actually golfed

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms thanks! There went some effort into that answer!

Answer (score 4):

## 1. - Python 1

```
print 1
```

This is the beginning of the chain. Good Luck to all!

Answer (score 4):

## 18. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1889 bytes

```
“ĊƁ²ḃ7BpṠƊ}œLṣQgƝḳ>ŒCẎu⁾ʋ2SẓŻ¤⁷İfṘʋẆ+ẠMċỌẏO[ƬqØẓḄvEḳĊıAĿṫvṀƥƓñðıL»;“FḂÇÐṄ2(ȦwÇọụTŀƑ'¢¬Ụḣġ1ṇ¡agx⁽ẈD,Ṫ⁶O³ḂṾɲ€shƈ'¹"F$i{S'⁹<Þ¹æ×$×ɼ/^çạȧæƈYĊ?dḳƓʠ)G¢⁵#®-[ṭ[Þċḳṛ\r6$ƙHṿụñ|ḳÑ(:ỵ©lɱ<ṂȦżḄȥ9ı³+f¤f/GẠK£p~ƁṚ£ḌBʂbṪṙTEµ1æĖ%ƙ¢>ṘœÑɦʠėỌÞ-ȧ*ẹ nṡGḣẊ6ṭs<SĠ3"¢ṅfḅḊq⁾ṫȧƤAẓe;ƭʂạ1ɲ⁽vĖ¿ɱ⁴ẒṁAẇṘ(Ṫỵḟkƭ0{ḷḥ}(ẈḣzẊ8Ƥḅ,/€ɗḄṪẹ½5ịİṗṗụ Ỵ;⁷ð®⁶Ð¥%ṠɗḲ)|ṢṘÆs⁺ƁȦḋ:Ri⁺)Ḣ⁸Ø÷`ṬẸṆ?ẓ.ụ×ĊḍɠqȧĠŀP{ḣẇ⁴ɲṇ⁴Ṿ]ṗʂİ⁾ṡWẋ1ɗʂẉOþɱ³ṅẉ`fẊṃÑƓ.Ɲ'½ỴṗŒ⁵%ṾƬȷị}Ðḥ_4ọẇụḳƓ€ṭịọ)ẇ⁺Ẇ^OÐhḳⱮċ-¹ṠÇƒḳọPẹ.Ɱ⁴HṣṾ}ȥ©BƬ⁶y¬tḂƓ¤IÆẏp{ọĖ&€ⱮỌm¤Sỵ¿¦`ẓċ~⁾ḷ f5Ø½ẠṭȧịṚẋƑ1¢YhÞmụṠẋgẆḂ!M^ƙÇŻȧỴ⁶Ɱ⁵ɱ7bhbṾƑÞÑJḄqḲØ©¶ṭṾ>ẓew,Ḷ@¿Ċ*¤m-<®þð¦ṚṄİėḥmḲKFṪ⁾)ȧµŻß⁼ȤƁụ[µ&@ċỊ_GƊḢþ¹ṡƘ\Ðtw2r⁹ṗḌḄGŀṘiṠøhɼ⁵9)ØỵṠ^tṢÆ⁹ç4Ị~ḷẉ¹⁴Ė=ṡṛỤ0S]HỌrGɱ€MvØṢẎU`..¿Ñ}⁸QƁCƝñJḲ⁵Ṁœðỵ⁸ḳ}ụọɱṪwḋowÐṡes°ẈDœẏỤ⁷Ṡ@©Æȧ@{ẈLė¹paw:⁾£×ʋŒḟµị¢ị÷X¡fẊ-ȷ[Ẓc¤<*ȧ<YɱzF{ḞȮİ⁾c(ɠḌ9ẉ×ŒjSṠỊ<PṬZẆHṭṢ®ṖṢḌƁGøZṡƥÇ-ḤḟqFẏfọCfPŻṂʋœ⁽SṖ^ɼṙẋɼịṣḢḶ""¬ṾQẉDʠ⁺⁸LṘ°`BĊıḥX8⁷ ẸḍṚ><ṁ¢ḥ]>rḍKQgṆ67j£¹ỵḟ;¬BĊƬỵNḟ'Ç£¡ċọh¥ṗȮƑYżŻẓ©Ṃ7×ḍṛ{p+`68¶Ọ¦ịịY6⁽6SỌp`Ṿ=½ȦRẉƥḢẎPDBĖg3ḃḄ2l¡⁴8ẹn!Tŀ5İtṙʠgĊð+Hq⁶ḅẒJ⁴ðpÐẉƝµÆƭƲṪƙḷ×p⁾'w-ụṢṭB⁴&Ọḥ9sẆıh\&%%ƲƬẇḍụḄ¡Ẹṇrʠƭ!$vṭmṘĖ1Çḟ⁵ẊpœẇỌcøḋṄƈĖƇⱮŀO¶ʠeṗ÷ ḍ⁸ṫ¢×⁸⁻Ṡżṿȷẹ©£ƇKẹI÷¥eḍ¥ƊƬ{Yẓṅ)ṣç½¿2v@ƙṙ<×ƲẋdƑH"BʂĖ&ȯḅƓṇġḷỊṠƓs⁾°¥_÷Ṙ⁺ṅ6ụkIkṁŻḟdR¬ƭ⁼÷?¥xƒṁMAị5ḣ+⁺ḂṾ⁸oɦDlȮ2³ƓỌoṬ1ØgḢCQjʋLṀ?}+®³{ßỌ&}kh\#<(ọs¹J&<ƲŒȥ~ṛt=ṇỴƥh6ẋ/ cạ⁷jỊėSKtÞ]ḅḋİẏȦʂṅƘṂẋẹ⁶⁼mḳṠƊþȷṣxḤżṃ®ėÞS⁶Ɓ¬ṗAṫ{Ç*ẎWCŀUḟɠ½6J⁵5Ị⁶Ṿẹʋf-ʠɗȮ©KỊ°°9çƒẏSḂṂ[¦¶%_lRĊ⁵Ġ#?]VnḊ]HrỌ⁷:ẉ¿wOḃ9ZɗɠuḞŒƁEṚnỴ⁶ƥƙṢk]2çuN½ṙqṁsȤȯḣBỌdIṃ?ƑṀė2ṛƬẏġß%⁷tRmỵI⁴Ẇ6ẏ QİEṁƁẹçȤH8Ṁ©¦ðLɲẈ&ȤkÇṗgḲƈṫŻṀġOṂkƙsẊḅḣḋXƙfQ?Ḳ!Bṫḷ°¹ṫỌʂlƥlȧỌ⁹ȦẒ@ḳ2¦KỌƓṀʠḂọḅ³Ḣ¡ḥ6ʠ$Ṗ\ṅ/ṿɲ⁺2;Eg'ṣCṛ]ɱṃø5Ẓ[¢iỵỌ1²gḞAçÇɲƊvHþlʂżụ⁴Ċṿ¦ÇRƲpṡÑƤ-ḅAỊ-Ƙe?ȮȦBƁ⁷çŒ ẇṁỊṢɗḤ×£ƙ$ı^[Ị0®ẉĊØ⁴Ƙ)ẎṄs⁵ḣẇⱮcʠS¹9ṢṘĠ¿ÐŀGWHBżµḍƈ¿⁷ẉe⁹ġ>*ʂɼfỤ;Ṗa⁾ʋ¦Ḍ|¿ỵẒ?6⁾N*ṪḶ8Ṫİ⁻ĖvẋȤḂḣAƈṅ³ÞWʠ×Tİ^⁶ɼßḥ'7*½ɗḊ+YḟṘ¬ȥG3µọḳṣĿṇ-ḳʋṡȯẸjṢ5Ẓ+3<Ỵmƒ6Ḳ^€ŀṇẒḶ^8ṇịɦẎṗHMKK²⁺JvƬṢ€Ð&ÑuE⁶¢3ż'Ȧ¹ḋ⁻w€⁸Þ\m9ÆḍZƇæ⁺"ȮƘU]ṾWʠ⁸|Ɠṣŀiẹ©uḃẋðƑ$ʂJøḥƭṠrvẊ@ṪḍAƑḂẒÞ'ÞȤEṚ!ẊṆỤpṗȯÐ<_5ṬyZṇẉwÞ¦ĠċE⁷,ɠȧẒ:ƭḊ²ẇaXqȷ!⁵ 8÷Ṫ⁾oẓżʋẸṾ¥Ṭż¬¶ḟ$\ɦØ⁸¡ɗnṬ’“$ẹGọ`ƬỵUPṡṀȷæŻ#ƥɠ²'⁴_ṀƇ÷ÑḃḤżtṅAḢẊė2ṭƒnṛ|ṡdĖqḌ"®⁺©ßf⁽|ṡçƓẠḳḲIÇXƘȦ²J€¡aȧ9CÆb{Dr©`QḲ&Ṭo`tṀ7Ḳẓɓị$ÇıMỌɱ¿ƓB½¡ṙgɦʂ!ḄŻ)⁾6ƊȦxẈn7»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVeLUhPZFv0VQAQR0QGvPJSRlwqKDiLjVeQhPngooDwUdBArQSGYgJJQRWDmCp2QToqZwCQo0KcbQtU5nVPd@YuTH/Gu01ZRRZI@j73XXnut3c97h4be/viRdf3P9HI33RXah4r6EUEU7p1OL98UZLO1n38V2rfL6UCD0D@/zrpTGV9Zm9CX0waNZN0HZqJPkNWMT@hzxUJXbpk@YSwI/UtLB4@PslUsFNrHias4wvSayTrzWJB/JgRxcZUvsyRLmMmb1LiEAK4JbYZ52JIgH8tOWdFJ5hHGojDU39Mu7i@kYRoXRkRom2aoVBAPDT3qf5N1Hwl9/soZQf7Ouvdb6DccIUjK3s3OxMcH@HwhJXnX8p9NtRVm3aSarVPCoiyYz4L24bluFhN6yIqxKJ9vN701TxEhX84oRY00nHXvnaA7JR2CbHewdWSkfRPkr86x8ny@1iTIMaJiyXf4lflPXRTGHt0aspPVgsxY0fQh0rXUKjNJvxX30UjfuUag0kw3R95ztyB/0k2hLdRnZh4jZkHWfr9K90pZ1Fw5yddo@DKQTC8zvx3NKGYQOLL1Eit2Wugk54UgoUZkL3RvOcIar24zlfN5NCzIbJ/QZoXmHUVpgK0V45E6oN57iW9nZpBiKeBwH02YK/TYTmbd34UeEMSNJR7cdkqGYewJbWOQb/8yJbQDoanTp4Aq7voDl1VyYD575hwQtYNITa7XCT26IAyfmRAkKP8MNUcY3y@BDSxBd1AKtkTVk2CR3LJb9E4QxLnK5sazbp27rajQfBfvPMOXIqEBbI2tsoMeQeJC1wSZq0H0ZyXEQdMrtEVbGbVippJ23Z5y8vcgB3sXFJC5kFQXAsjMmAkn@9A9oftK7aBM/FMLS9moAhDCl54@JCPIB@bny2f510J6hIixNR1AsRFqisetA@Q0DQJq6sP/SO4BIUN1aIHsAToe4@ciJwQdfO9uYUsDeJ5N7pi@EkqQMPPwgGSLsXgbMJ3FE0QJymzihmlLpVv1PA583tL4K3CVL9PIdTaHbhmZwhZzpQAXYQ8qP0wjbZJZxzTaAzxM33uZoHaQ03eBrSJ4XUFAVkyGRP5E0txfSsPtA2x9WMZMFPzUjxBxSe6tbr7GPGlDrv6Oy52g9uxkxeOBxzJxP1tn/huo7SiKhcO36L5MlqQuSxpNnhHafi09Nr2naWS4pJrusBSqHJXXko9mAjzV1GHsbL7mtGGqyIrRvbTBNrLuQysC0htqB90rqJXC4H3YyFHTMEtJtEJ8tZMtvZosG0N7Sh5pC4iiMe0CWZ5JMLUB@xChVhVBR0BSonS/ApXYHJazGErkfS8Jq3@iBCibK7/iSPQpZOKXtq4mgDjWCMbPxG9NYD8oqH@@23P2LD1m/mmQrpW7G/hXlkTmaBCc7kLrJXAPnqGE0xJHY9FOIqtJEPblpJSmUO84TUjNSS@jargJnEdctXSLzVmx2ik8umkGKRl5NHkRWNBNFsz40qDEBt1DrdCvho8d3KchSccS66AD3fiERqpPW7Hqdjv5xzVwfN3acej85JStAJIqJMjA0@dtsqyGt/o2OuUBatvkVClMdwRZkelpC9zdyLQHEliVeUqEhtbdGL2GQPuQSUPf7bQBjUI8yxAEnLbSbR9Cg0AV/JdEgjbhmP28PGgtSbXi4isZBVwHIrCCVZroqZcijoLfr0TiObJftUUw4TLEz43kNLXr8hh@am7tRyOXVzynmyi0oy@XaBybOUR87zd8LWQePAtJUiwOUDA2aO1wf3v6EDHqy3QLgVawoHP6X1MjxT3llWClsQDeySb0tZcjhXJ0yMIIhCP1Kz2yoncQL1dlCvrn21fqzZX@87AzMKpsiIZAkEp05Itc2MkFMwEerWWUftPLEsVNUM59qaF64AaWscQIKo2jvtI9Nse3ObTmb74GprHgCMpSOFnitBgkbbse6wuk32lq1ThKYiYHOgtOnuS7yBPqoS06AvKRhhxl84xlFL6dmw/72x4GnuZKKUxO25Ds070jklJQnIUnDKiiGh/5vLnCPWjXtKuF7meUXqDEgLq2KClK/qFhFsSnrBtlVWA85BgSBnHeopvc04xP19kBVXuxnqoc0E@1Szcms0WoNIvRI3pcNlGLzMhaNQsiTd33lPub8uBOUCLrX0DCsdxjhmSXGV45FSyPS1YnqPqQgferUgfJbDmyHLw@CAqgeNrG0zs0zrfR/eyghqpvuLSbW3Uo2gXod7Hc4rg0In9pR68MWTtlFBKLxF@C2KVstR8lbGh9nvGBc66a6WK6Q79NsQ0sKJgeHOg8UX0KnBmn5EZBNd9NByz1PTjyCs0P8L5zdaAciZzLeQLrA0efI3Az2Nb8iq13OT4pXUv/YkVhEWSWQxdgFRheiBRG9@GwY/WYflgKWJLNN2giiewHumMG2XobVmFMQncE61CAKeaBOX@@15B23UXitkKPykGhPZijV3KKpHBwxtdXkoETWjt0qxkPgF6iisUAi/6lzYFipoNG6f7Jh0N3TGzbM5UTNV3/fQFL72oaQ9bI4qIUuePJFvC56oEdtJXXkIl0gLuvovle/JR1DFQoZXiwq4zFXv8GiyBro0B@3IrIUm7W46Sn15FJDfcDVzNYBtQkTb@YIbZxEpe8ugPv2LvujAhzAPFLTquZwAVuaLgOwbUiTZXYCXpFWeImLFifL7Aig6AwCaJmu3wekEiJcZmhFmQ1yNfGpelK1KEsvvt8ra@1Bgtz67EQnAISRH4yFjIzQ1wdkgaFbAkGBD1Qi0qU0SgQW5AsdGUUiRVcWZuVc14YPaWp5RklHzrWiVKeA/3lpKOXXbraX4jSNSC/LinfH5h2AQd20PAzKUXGQindRbzrdSzGPPYu9040sdRQZgZ1NlRpJGA6bJd57vBdjMIhjAwRiOksKOwt4au9NdaOFa3nbjnuxNKBHGeScjsNEpYDT4QF0YBr@WayuwO//gKB1j9BadAt3/kqxofP6O1x2fQ/x5nkzpOM0kZJ1c8xyVTgUEtpV@O9pvr0IWxDW@Tz9Fgajf6pF/CYocunMzP2IUQ9cgnZP3JmciijtvCOHssU9UAN9DH122k5rWn7qNrf0lEMc2UCZLciEklts04WDGCy9XsZhQV/NxPdoJF9iFbT1MKK0/RIZuMtbge1pfrHLbXxvLSxRadJNuUoL13mG4Z/EgLJdO05UpBYF5@vBimHeaAc5e6GBUtP98jJU9vvrnQ61WdHHSSCTbeam6ks3I0J0JGEsZotFTD/66uIhobPpw8LrSiIovmQwaQckDAwrncOV2Fw0hYfcA@LYnMe7GP1LobB1D1pWdo7SZrNtOuZI4ivpRHoPpbg/vzMzA0psCqHeSpjAMRb68C0WIfGADB6gK0XsnUrInsr15ka54D0iLSof9lS9cMLkKm3D5x8Pk3ipSJqKqYPwR6csRVQWA9cxNGaFy9TuufR/VHrIBe1zqmUginno5fy3elQvjBBw1PS@uIocxz2pm3kd9pRyRONhuwgRv541rWGV6N8JNEI3Hsc@7x725lzXNYBi6aNE1yF7uziDef7Q/la5WEHzO/4HoQLNgfaSkf0Og2/zQM49S8M5KGn5grmvYU8Oa/rGF82@uCo8gGkaVmOl6ixtnudee7zVeC/ewPI46XLilU1sLnHU1fG6FZPK1YUIMqXPbjIVYFvyM2GlPvymcdM3kKvYQI/5sv1MBuEvNaPN5uZXDhi2igCFOXca0XfQEdeVFDjx4//Aw)

I believe this gives me a score of **2427**.

Text before and after the long string of digits are each compressed with `“...»`. The string of digits is compressed individually into a base 250 integer.

Whenever a long ASCII submission gets posted it is a prime time to score some points.

Answer (score 3):

## 4. Javascript ES6, 89 bytes

```
alert(btoa`ã­·ã}ºã½yë_uã­{ïNú÷½ûßÏ}÷<ßÏvÓN8ïÝ»ï_8óN´ÛÞýó]wÛ®üë®»óO4`+' 6|Er{"()[]{}"@m')
```

Base64：

```
YWxlcnQoYnRvYWDjrbfjfbrjvXnrX3XjrXvvTvr3vfvfz333fzzfz3bTTjjv3bvvXzjzTrTb3v3zXXfbrvzrrrvzTzRgKycgNnxFcnsiKClbXXt9IkBtJyk=
```

Comment: @user202729 Because you wrote `&#127;&#247;` while it should be `&#247;&#127;`. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

## 6. [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 196 bytes

```python
print('disp('+''.join(str([ord(c)for c in"alert(btoa`ã­·ã}ºã½yë_uã­{ïNú÷½ûßÏ}÷<ßÏvÓN8ïÝ»ï_8óN´ÛÞýó]wÛ®üë®»óO4`+' 6|Er{\"()[]{}\"@m')"]).split())[:-1]+",''])")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYmxasJAAIZfJdxyd0SFohSRDl26pg8Qj8SqxSuaC5erEmKeoUNHsR0cRTOkEIhmuf/BUp2@j@@LU7NQUb9tYy0jw@hMJjGjLqW9DyUjlhjNfKVnbMrflXamjozIZDnXhr0ZNQlxsCdb4ZDb@qZNimPweW8ZCg81Ktvggl985aie7lzj2xuiwN5eUARDlJ79ww4/aFCKDXb2jCuO9nzb5esgdKnzuH3R2Zgw7ossH5PnFeVE8F4SL6VhnPuj7oNwSYdSwQlv238)

Not bad for score, 135 bytes shorter than the previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

## 7. Java 8, 209 bytes

```java
v->"print('disp('+''.join(str([ord(c)for c in\"alert(btoa`ã­·ã}ºã½yë_uã­{ïNú÷½ûßÏ}÷<ßÏvÓN8ïÝ»ï_8óN´ÛÞýó]wÛ®üë®»óO4`+' 6|Er{\\\"()[]{}\\\"@m')\"]).split())[:-1]+\",''])\")"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LZDNSsNAFIX3fYpLNjNDbUAQKVbFjUvjQnCThHaapDI1TUIyiZSYZ3DhsqiLLkvbRYVCazdzHyxOaDf355wLl/ONecE7Y/@19kKeZfDARVS2AEQkg3TEvQCsZgV4kqmIXsCjz7HwoWA9rVYtXTLJpfDAgghuoC46t0aiLyUlvsgSStqEmONYRDSTKbXj1KceG8UpePqFY/AwSCUdypgPcK6WaovzSu30eJjiop83WolrC3e4VQfc4w9@VLi9bnqBn1YX1/il9rjud3FjqV@c4TcecOO@4Uyt8A8XaqXtzePFoE3g8v0@LR3HMSiz3bJqprsJYY7hMjNLQiEpY/ZV59xtO8YZIa52mFH3mpBJPgx1yFPWokEw0aTokYrtAmcnTNNMBhMzzqV5xBCZHo3yMGQnYlX9Dw)

Comment: Which charset? In UTF-8, it's 209 bytes...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oops.. looked at the characters on TIO instead of the bytes. Thanks.

Comment: If it's ISO-8859-1 or something, it can be 1 byte <-> 1 char. Just specify this is your answer (not even in your title)

Answer (score 3):

## 17. [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 4316 bytes

```java
import java.math.*;interface Main{public static void main(String[]args){BigInteger k=new BigInteger("361465645787803556642041740125333791157289109836690832678496621620620476938008188755961262952961045044334883735032022649132976542429391791957032215373603493060060908973231820754365849983880098639334885407908312678706946342237930056305671352578126483085654455450990325300036187422582180640564627709845866957795417075379794457771084260885275651423270277115376273619152526268960916671775297982081324848038299273109785484955540448632255751457983092806398161815414681140205940443983929094227240892016130222081735443463765266530750906013199766831562981062206883501821081948064356413314877295359005754551748620326652056931891130304022998598456117784613831331553499645105355499572823602652224584622340127230019203445570907108390902756251280829226959356401632317493087775163844632433847320732669180722866971084641603496667699643270544307016691969256813927566081197091024786683700593068316853133329853126916980565101295672302657842521145965496959516667557604187718961737197699807729922479014391244358641964407038005042698897145981486166558111528268648754750105761790156735705908529827044494532735373542074188931773995823743175708985242811138374833461925235558545552543239298858693639120903294102768096905451200672090144132989460345783811846857389850888625728879562355642107076889151634052467151465205669235281987289146702267527528337652765227579834772607096297867378167970398026817606005667187750254267940709328271716135213654213584876566950507963838908925435608432108543211988380043373863076684282181314428196820459900560624029445930562805108606439494597377667022934949909491248650257423941442501130465637115392123710138139320285578930995693580243682019990534044973098092357106401611806537055780798006419839968127797560014488960920640815497049798937939978802170728965447020215687663299085285135712460422589432498713019435076232304133799479163312692117165385441054909324684626318749880002741865347863181414553280961072341916597070153405988301052811964133454660365664326014933265975677282033389713733987900066870015915215592230373098864436569203037855204983481186013802629322959015235254953356454611632992424153992307118239942840069852191457611354149092159274929329165426494771788810351821419395270672924908000688485483415366648629467837741559472196172641833145440295355695638904300466360749980832149475326839625824180597090035758161747631566626294378588544433795467707770969803888994908945743924524092368150546763216300781506983452769047662620172149595341272974866879383765780753650149826124453578901148919524983399484586399519164831435118868114641416056484708317549382655513941592665766107754640311775988857536833503400184150046460874444462574370426007012825320369557554303147313398461850454111000186338871401985456785254838518366172829415397040132093408711221497234248435036427390549018005682773833150973835234655369632873294078395344645151807175961277939873402540463065930241499535840653603495768603632925007799294792786898241888229504684122524052210587758223645174725998848750958165288764789127336269132371823288331209150791866640989489138808098191189590355822424507961982835596641625445961077819053329957513727274473281659012240134633338620306528063546531509291823793582673621854840157379632497150667941992447112735994344255393555754542931084167792498011617817577811858484359459303990519025217546545426128120668058213732780269207184049475513140841508071171466489179571732148022085619865421226980087686463817810882555691541238702979414090919943348838792478685887433470060823164562205755506913403025258116930323322200035144350860063326517842814125393604394558124262604094433995875688276997577049389085643903344779813236853388709369241795685568599627908894295210291487809974734882698802431466163144590822266263386642120435740609962270983909896397378387628019919833263785731297232046119724885501188522648477713389060005303782524378329767919011556972617597217583067932552147331643458090790141659918288419722529366943890533673108818328410954166228146653384682119894555378618098353742188919187416715990821349955676320230531868940883985817821677233033834934236649460409157978074244277935");BigInteger a=new BigInteger("27884");while(k.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)!=0){System.out.print((char)k.mod(a).longValue());k=k.divide(a);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZhLa13ZEUb/itIjKRCx37UL40mgBz0IgXTIIKEHN5YiX8t6IMtugvFvd9Y6BDqQpk3LuufuXfW9qk5/OH05/eHp@fbxw8399@/nh@enl9eLD/zy@uH0@v7692/Oj6@3L/86vbu9@NPp/Pj1@fM/P57fXXx6Pb3yny9P55uLB35/@fPry/nx7h@/nF7uPl19/eP57ie@d3f7cnH/9vH214vffnH5Q191rLnGjB279DnXGq2MGqPUNnvvkbXOaDtryd3XyrJ7W7FHrtXqaoV/R6zsu5Rd9445c9W2Ws7GD2XMMkbvY@8efZbeSmtrZO0tY83RRsuelVtyBp@2OnlulT6yl1X4lwszeut1txJz9DW5m1I2F@ZePY/D5yhhadXaoqwcq4/WKL@XMlfnT9Q@G33yyNi97Mn1Y04KzOTmyYMFOHbwvblb3WUNvjZWi@CmMTfdz4icwEMpnB3JCRFRyx5tFcpowbF1tN6i8L1qOxzAuVm5HVzWTpqqi3oiwCiSxjZ4jD1gYLdMngftoClanZQIhHRKWTM4fPKVXrJRYM9dKblS0li71lFamenzfNKzZUm6iTYAsRUe7cDvdXDBM4AECW0tmg9wAO7aa8LMAsoJibtCMCRD3yxQQKc1h9B0oKm917EjILvPBGgImhPxbFTRPZdy0EZFPlzdC/XR357CuSoA7EFN3MVBc0J6IsVaOG3ys7priKFxTmsQABetq8xosFVpqUsh9BQ56LRbZKDNCjpAidZypqXSvCIKdUXF4Lj6HgDQUOceKKyEFSe8R2tyfdBKk4caF4Qty5NZsSvBkTyeK9sEe9DmZkRQa1JQLW3EFscAF8VMl2tPW0X7/kBtdeUuKoaeEonSFs2CClKBTawEDrZAuRRAqwtzUj@ILkgM7qIqSg51w5VZKtzXRoUIdlDewBpFe@JErtzYyZM3zC1OnZOK0eZGmRgDBlECFATncxhFdQCGXcSNVANtjRwTGLpWxcIlKGnDckSHNCiLwV/41qZPHO4FkIws8CpOoDkInluxYAogVaq4Z6OVZfVFR@YAxFi7gACQwyl5EH5WxzBANi6HG/DqXAFXe0b3TpyIApXPxq7L24i1Cg4chxYlH2@3gQmnAahM4ZGAQN77iDs@M6pCSzcK1yj@4a/6b4D44sDEJPAMFTiRRCgYDw5x2DK/pj6Hr1nok9NSMrKDNvbXj/DczUF@wv9cYMhAVST6pBmNOzUbWuzaT7iQGIaEUrRLx8SbjgVoUgsDDyHPRa7As7akFCKgmVZpFGIOJLeXNk7ZJGGDI@w4ETveIzhU0V5WTiTynOciDYzsyOhHuGWr0I18uw4w3TciRQyEqs6fgEFmUwqxAovdbOI2ArWIN189vFmNW/RU/DbN05vixdL0gd9Bli4kfh/52fyauQfiwwxNo57kYiw04xkKzXc64u/4k@5QzKHiPasXw345oj5BdMA6jZFt5ByJjSSL8RaZeAq5HHYFeEibHRLQJpdLJbIjl1Z3cqRTCdFiCB4zAPh1BTnCrSlkNEiCMQwWmBshIjJlU8/plDxidcxBlnTlQHXEMrnFf6cwhLFYiBGdDP8oDqcCGF0C0XTSkKbEAZF7QI2xHZzLwORXUIQ0FLG2MfOVLMzD/tTzGoHumP@uBli2HuBh5SHnEEfeMg34EakNrtbodDWMDdClY7ChCkJxpCfb8XDyY5wKSwyWPh0ogNHZFUJrcwMM2crGDIy/7n0knwMFs2P0AFt6G8F1JBQn1u0UgpFyjCG6RJwYh4hGqIv5ES4M7i3V62GCLMa3JBVfLhIBfEhiOkyDbcbZx3rjnaLleuES4@gHfcJW36fTGjWmNeMhQo/6CRWFjWhxMU8DHOCVEv5iibkxku5MXlBogaoIeFplrKWzEx7TvFyHFwBgyj8BbazTIv7ChmO7NKncLg/HgmL@Ki6QYwxMONrHWgBKzjHYZNS5JhHzXIGgGNdaG6IYBdSEQPkMc3XHs8okVCmBS9jeoJqcpROQxT4o3n@MWoByvBQ1jTwBGfWmCwuBxWFM2KpSERP5DF3MhOJpWIuUZnPB7YQ8HKs90g11QH1V7HnIjguQKvlPGXyjNpHTTq5OVkfGM4EOX1bnHbHDSFIe7Db@gLCJLrohXNsORwzEdMEfLh7T4Q82brBhnvDMMLlplwlueDalrc6QPRY/dgNw25qV8whIAMQhxkbD/4wjVba33ipmBXUrEiYJjnc08FH3dpTXyGul7zKmGqcTbJEjZDFGX64M3cDFe3xkKrFqOC0AEpsUZyIPux0TN0wBJKCn8QXXgNQxWYCakeam7nrT3IOPaEKkZrRed9PsgSKhGKCsBVQ5AgoAw/RxxyuWyB6KZOYBM0bfx9rNfUxF3hGONZZQYcQIO5TpBEdhNVKGTLJHIOHugIFolwM3Sd8N3MEYrGE0bFSPILa7RRhdjkyYz2OsdecL9bs6KeHjAIhkfBiNxZ2eOISUYpRDNGUdgTCdmeXQtfyT8cPI8bWEORHmBt9pvjKA3DGtXSx945F54NhWxdZB@eSP63jrhLHbPXohXrBq/vc1aNuLyiBXwt@FrzmAhm2ny7aeMSsAGoBpxw1t2WGDGh4wrKoLniMc8B0M1aXRUdMEkMmGq13t4BzV4Jw0wVzPmCAU6toojMUccCy6CjBU4INpqshcVrUmfgOuIRj8yj/M5ObbFlrzNY8tLX0NQHDEV9jksWc6@UWS/KsqjB6BzVGJdtzHGEKE2fAljxObb1mu8Ezu7kIiVK4qQOcmQJeGMTnSdD1fXq7azbc/1xLfvtoRcEwYh6P7F2p24Ok4D/Sl03dNHpcoxoduDwXDBOYj3gNpiCZkg6zevlq4cKp/pY07vZQD07fh4T3gtHxlY6hxBQ8U3xHpVEJ8uerupsfWJimsOWze2tMNGhxcSdP1obqPuqSgVFNmHvOjMG4xl1mCSoEI5UB30xYoAtK2r8vsaMv5epCN3dLhgePHEWXzh6s3//N/Ak7/938C8MUePPTr@/PH28v763dPD8@nl9u/Pl3@9tT133/8y5@vfve2XH39@d@fXm8frp8@v14/v5wfXy8v370/vVzdXz883Vyerq4/Pj3e/e308fPt5dXVm/u399c35y/nm1s@evPt27fv3/8D)

No one likes unprintables :)

Comment: I know it's too late now; it's not a code-golfing challenge; and due to the encrypted 4,000+ bytes number those few bytes wouldn't matter a lot anyway, but as a Java code-golfer I just wanted to say you could have golfed the actual code to [**4273 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y8x23fcr). :) Also, this validates the rule "_Each new answer must be in an **UNIQUE** language, check the list below before posting an answer._", but changing it to JDK 10 is valid, and could have even saved [more bytes: **4261 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y8olzo7t). (JDK 9 is fine as well for your current answer.)

Comment: Building on @KevinCruijssen [2808 bytes](https://ideone.com/h032Ky)

Answer (score 3):

## 27. Python 2, 26028 bytes

```
import zlib,base64;print zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b"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"))
```

Nothing fancy, but it is after all my first ever codegolf. I deliberately kept it ASCII friendly, just for you, @hakr14. And yes, Python 1 and Python 3 have been done, so I'm just filling the gap.

Comment: Ha! Thanks!

The reason I want to keep it ASCII only, for the record, is some languages (esp. esolangs) just can't deal with non-ASCII text. I'd like to keep this as accessible as possible.

Answer (score 3):

## 28. [Win32 EXE, 231624 bytes](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JHd8xwRQHy/)

Self unzip program

Comment: Aaaaaaand we’re done here.

Comment: can't wait to see someone try to output this monstruosity

Answer (score 2):

## 10. [Sclipting](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 993 bytes

```
丟뫉뚑뫸꾍먹겇멉겇멚뢈먹겇먹겇먹겇먹궸멙겗멺몝뫈놫멻궲묊낭뛾늨뚞뢗띞란땞꾙뙾뎢뒏겐뙉뇧뚹맰뙩낭뫘린몪뢠멋늛묊낛띎뎹딮뒔뗿겥뒹닮뜈곬뚋닪뙻뗨띨돰딉몣묊늄럾뢋딎뎁뗾뢵듮뢒뚎뚱럾낈띾늎띎뢃뛏겐똫돮럻곦땺곣랛닮딨껨뚨뇨되뗫램냯뜙닧딘뛪랙럫땩듪떛귬뗘돤떺뛭듉듭됨귧둋껫뙙곤똊껰뙨늀멛꾘몪랛몈몲몺낝몋릂묉궆뛾뎁듿겦뗪뫨뙚뗨떸껨떚뇨뙛꿯떋꿫떚럪둻뇰뙈릎묉궝뚎놱똞늒딎떤럏겤띫맯뛋뛧뚪루띨런딊놁몪꺙멩놸묉것딎늙뒮몧둎뎐똿겐띘꿩럹뗩뗛러띺뗩떋럤럙듨랛돮둨다됪닰뙩늀몪뒻먹랞묉겤떯겥램곤둸뫮땊룰딙랭뫹뮭목뎕뫻릡묊놌뛞뢾뗎몓땾뒵뜾뚾뜮뚓똏겥됪뇣뙘룤띋듮떈듨똋룦떻냯뗩뗤딋뫤뙙런딈뢐멊낓묊낶뒾낡딿겥럫닩뙈꿰뙋뚰멺뒖몋떽멛릻멙뮜묉궗둎랧뗞낡듯겑듩닩땹뫰뙚뢎멊랹몋릤뫨낶묊놪랏겦똩믦뒉귫딸밋
```

Stickin' with the theme...

This can be run in @Timwi's [EsotericIDE](https://github.com/Timwi/EsotericIDE).

Answer (score 2):

## 12. Pyth, 2017 bytes

```
Fb[19999 47817 46737 47864 44941 47673 44167 47689 44167 47706 47240 47673 44167 47673 44167 47673 44167 47673 44472 47705 44183 47738 47773 47816 45483 47739 44466 47882 45229 46846 45736 46750 47255 46942 46976 46430 44953 46718 45986 46223 44176 46665 45543 46777 47600 46697 45229 47832 47536 47786 47264 47691 45723 47882 45211 46926 46009 46382 46228 46591 44197 46265 45806 46856 44268 46731 45802 46715 46568 46952 46064 46345 47779 47882 45700 47102 47243 46350 45953 46590 47285 46318 47250 46734 46769 47102 45192 46974 45710 46926 47235 46799 44176 46635 46062 47099 44262 46458 44259 47003 45806 46376 44776 46760 45544 46104 46571 47016 45295 46873 45799 46360 46826 47001 47083 46441 46314 46491 44524 46552 46052 46522 46829 46281 46317 46120 44519 46155 44779 46681 44260 46602 44784 46696 45696 47707 44952 47786 47003 47752 47794 47802 45213 47755 47490 47881 44422 46846 45953 46335 44198 46570 47848 46682 46568 46520 44776 46490 45544 46683 45039 46475 45035 46490 47082 46203 45552 46664 47502 47881 44445 46734 45489 46622 45714 46350 46500)=+kCb)Fb[47055 44196 46955 47599 46795 46823 46762 47336 46952 47088 46346 45441 47786 44697 47721 45496 47881 44163 46350 45721 46254 47783 46158 45968 46655 44176 46936 45033 47097 46569 46555 47084 46970 46569 46475 47076 47065 46312 47003 46062 46184 45796 46122 45808 46697 45696 47786 46267 47673 47006 47881 44196 46511 44197 47016 44260 46200 47854 46410 47344 46361 47021 47865 48045 47785 45973 47867 47521 47882 45452 46814 47294 46542 47763 46462 46261 46910 46782 46894 46739 46607 44197 46122 45539 46680 47332 46923 46318 46472 46312 46603 47334 46523 45295 46569 46564 46347 47844 46681 47088 46344 47248 47690 45203 47882 45238 46270 45217 46399 44197 47083 45801 46664 45040 46667 46768 47738 46230 47755 46525 47707 47547 47705 48028 47881 44439 46158 47015 46558 45217 46319 44177 46313 45801 46457 47856 46682 47246 47690 47033 47755 47524 47848 45238 47882 45482 46991 44198 46633 48102 46217 44523 46392 48139)=+kCb)+++"puts "NkN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVW7bhwxDPyVgzvjGj34UpHKQEr/QDpXAdwYiFPk6y@c4WrXSJErFgKPIofDIfXx5/Pn4/H97Udf@buJR/ebmE/H2eQmsqTnOU157ga7xTrP3iy/Q9q/Pv895w3eVdhj4jwDX/ybGDKmymFHLjFkichbOkZaLAQ@Pg1oFdmHZjRbMvB12GU24NcJn57xdQXsYxAPfczylqrQx4mwNdiX71weE2gVudyD9YIZt9WBYcwLW@/IPhC5NeCcsGfGzG4Kf@mIbIN5A@xZaH5lWJD5TvsgZlSktC@FpSGvTVFytc68DszecSt7gVomONGqXRf5CUSb4CG5asyFaFnGvqt9FXuCmL3tWrJE3PW1Lt5oaYaMjfaBsyV2nBUxW5tnjRO3EjT7ZY2cI3tv@GYy@LPvYyFyQAnKjDbhb0EkrdET2jCBMrMiRBByq4PRiit@s4W8izgjyh/89wFtZME4QzlCPs3gk7VQA@AkKRbqAdj4Td06dTVOPbBS97IsaIMdTD2UHf0SdiEYXwoVNVw9mpOzsKgTp6cE8YxTA0rMxSGjHRwa2NCGSbHUKc@6fZIrKpC9KGaM6lWq5cAjuvWQc0ceBnVFbqkl09aev93fX96ec11kWC3ARnGiQGWzvNo3OFCUx5y2BZxgggLmgHOxkEDhuLkPiF@WncC6XWLmvzZUeGuycRxqkmOFh@QsZEwSJsXpJHBRGEoMQpG3007SsqtspdWYjN3WErn14FCw3k5yosW5KA5h1Hq5Fl1G@FIL72o/l0AJ/hDb4AiHUswYvewGyTcKHrVn@MQWrcYf46yrFiYzavlwIQgbHWifj8WhEIqTfAorGsZlxTF3iiToyZWb4vdzWVW9WvYgtslFwS5zpRhXevGWdyd9mBc@x1AfXTiWGJ@YQ8D9izaIGeLPzYS@U7p7weKZsOG0c5BnLaXiM2rh9C1ybcJBNj5qFvuhsYGnoQYzEeoealfx/TDlBMc1IHNtvWXXeIvaOzD0Wox1vjCkXthT24Ocddmuy0uftRy4uGrkq8bdR/ZlHQ8H9YZbwXVtzC5aXcDqjj7XMaT3@/3p4/fnr9vT6/vr4/EX)

Let's keep things ASCII friendly, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

## 13. [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 1125 bytes

```ruby
$><<"Fb["+'泫Aѹ୽Ñ຃Á຃°ʂÑ຃Ñ຃Ñ຃Ñ൒±๳mBय़൘\0੝ЌࡢѬɳάΊ֬ୱҌݨٻ๺ӁणёĚҡ੝2Ś`ɪ¿࡯\0੯μݑלٶԋ๥ّࠜЂพѿࠠҏԢ΢ܚ؁g\0ࢆ̌ɿ׼މԌɕ؜ɸѼљ̌ંΌࡼμʇл๺ӟܜ̏ฤ֐วͯࠜעఢѢढ۲ԟ͢ਛϱࠣײРͱ̟֡ؠկഞԲܦՐНف؝ۢണڿటұฦԀచҢࢊ¯୲`ͯ‚XP੭ƈ඄Ќމ؋๤Ԡ"ҰԢՒఢհढүଛտଟհ̠ڏचӂż൭Ѽख़Ӭࡸ׼զ'.unpack(a="U*").map{|i|47882-i}*' '+")=+kCb)Fb["+"".unpack(a).map{|i|481339-i}*' '+')=+kCb)+++"puts "NkN'
```

892 bytes shorter

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVLfbxJZFI7/wv4FZmKClWjUbrLdRDdREx@NLyYm@mC7DxvTuGnW7cNGjZ2phQLDT221WGAYKHZuGRmgVMCpJPgjwVAECoVqNedp3@9fUL/pdH883HvuOfec73znu/eP6Ym/9veP/XLunHB54obgdPxdXLvQqfxA@ubbMFVn34rY6sZHyfb@v5Ui9TxVivXQnYu0kqgHqfTs5mnSYm2Zkmon2yi2si3vTpb0fFf@urr7mirVbZHSqU74XbSbROLZ99FbDVavUTJnFeZa5tfwYHl3o@ejyspumJTltkTleKdGitIN9tSWuhcdir8hV3U15UZtYH7z9OTGwnC5Ue6YnaWmTExqobvZMj@62wcNE3vLzSCV0zshKr/YygFzoJKhdlRKq18KvcSWSqvPP@VJSQ0KbWUr30zsJIdKP0fr8V5hL9MPtWO74jD2RaX11OcaGYlunsqZ3gwZ0a5KqreeI71waytXl65fJU1/@GH@CG08asvfPENMke4pQtfoqf0IevYN9OzmKPu8X6Nsom80lc9BSke3pffmESrpHZNWlrazlCwPzH7GcWr696nxXyePj58Xrp0QRk7dGZ@6d//2/R9/Ghs7e/L2gxOOow6nMHLeOXlpYuTg6QTOxCxnL59yNhviWkXmbM7AesKZK8y1zceIY4k@zuQ8Z9Eq1zbCnGVUrr2KwJ/l2noB9WXc65wtqpwF/MhBfRB@ZI0zt4l72NkUZ0nUiBJnHliPgnMQcdH2vegrgocIDD96SrgP@4GD8wLiIfRdAA83chdf2zwCM1wrA0@KHfJAnhczvFxEDHU6/CA4loDjy2Meaw7gSwHEJK4VYDeAF8nAB1Y1Chxrzhw0AObmJrjpyFkFLs4BF/jCzmE9AqYL8fms3c/it/QM/FKos/TEPH7keIv2PPMG4gvwZziLyYcaIE9GvATrVg91LnLtzRr0BY/4qs0nPgcM9IxHMYdp9xND0AMYbuAnLV3Qz@VDHfQMrIAzfM8b@Armwmyv8GaFhK0TS9vvI@GdPDEb12/pxmAjNq4P@pQs3CT46DYfSTrA1apPcff4gJetF2aXLB0w33yEa3nYAPpo4ChDf8MQ/v2a//3KsTOjoz//8y0dh9/S6XQKU9N/3j0qXJm84tjf/w4)

Comment: The battle between ASCII and non-ASCII

Comment: @dylnan this is barely even golfed, UTF FTW

Answer (score 2):

### 22. [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 13410 bytes

**13410 bytes using Windows-1252 codepage.**

-8632 bytes!

```perl
%h=(k,'BA¶CBA¶C',U,'¶ADA	¶ADA	',e,'¶C	ABA¶C	ABA',N,' 	 	',w,'¶C	C¶C	C',V,' D ¶C	A	 D ¶C	A	',i,'¶CD ¶CD ',Z,' 	 	 	',T,'	¶C	C	¶C	C',I,' B B',R,'	¶AB 	¶AB ',g,'	¶C4*	¶C4*',o,'C¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶AB4* 	 ¶AB',x,'¶AD ¶AD ',j,'¶A7*	¶A7*	',M,'C4*	C4*	','m','¶AB4* ¶AB4* ',c,'¶CD¶CD',a,'D D D ',F,'B B ',u,'A	 ¶C	A	 ¶C	',h,'¶C	¶C	',b,'	¶C	¶C','s','B 	 ¶CB 	 ¶C',f,'¶AB¶AB',K,'D D ',L,ABAB,'q','¶C	A¶C	A',p,'¶AD B ¶AD B ',r,'¶AB ¶AB ',Y,' ¶C	 ¶C	',X,'	A	A	A',l,'¶A4*	A¶A4*	A',n,'¶C4*	ABAD¶C4*	ABAD',D,'			','y','¶¶',t,'¶CD 5*	AB¶CD 5*	AB',E,'	 	 ',v,'¶C4*	¶C4*	',C,'   ',W,BABA,P,'¶ABC¶ABC',Q,'	C	C',H,'C	C	',A,'  ',G,'	A	A',d,'¶AB 	 ¶AB 	 ',J,CBCB,B,'		',O,'	 	 	 ',S,' ¶CD ¶CD');$_="
AB4* 	 ¶CED¶AF	¶CE¶C4*	CG¶C	 	A¶CD4* 	 ¶CGB ¶AB D ¶C	8* B 	 ¶A4*	 B¶H D¶CD B 	5* ¶AB4* B¶C	4* 4*	 ¶C	7* 	 ¶CB¶CD 5*E	¶C4*	 	¶C	 BA	¶ABC	 ¶C	A	 4*	¶C	I¶C	5* B 	¶C4*	AB 	C¶AB D¶CBAB 	¶J¶AB6* ¶C4*	ABAD¶C4*	 4*	¶C4*	C	 4*	¶CD DAD ¶AF	¶CKDA¶C	4* ¶ABA¶C	 B¶C4*	5* 	C¶A6*	 ¶CD DAD ¶L¶ABA¶H 	¶CD ¶AB5* ¶C	 D¶AB ¶CBC	 ¶AB4* 	¶AB 	 B¶CD4* B¶AD¶C4*	 	¶C	6* 	A	C¶AD 	 ¶C	AD ¶CD4* 	 ¶C	AB 	A¶ADA¶J¶AD B¶CD DAD ¶CD DA4*	¶MA¶C	A	 4*	¶C	5* B¶CD 7*	 	¶CBC¶C	8* BA	¶C	 ¶C4*	 B¶H 	¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	AE¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶CD BNC¶CB 	¶C	 BA	 ¶4* ¶CD 7*	 	¶CBC¶CD 5*	 D¶CE¶C	A	 D ¶C4*	5* 	A	¶ADA	 ¶C	 BAB¶C4*	C	AB ¶CD B 5*	 ¶ABCB¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C	4* ¶C	CBC¶CD D6* ¶CD BA5*	¶CF	¶CGB¶C	A	CB¶CKDA¶AB 	¶C	8* 	4* ¶A5*	 	¶C	AD ¶C7*	A¶C	 	5* 	¶AB5* 	¶H D¶C	5* 	 ¶CD 	AB¶CKDA¶CD 7*	 	¶AB 	A¶A5*	¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	 	A	C¶ABA¶C4*	AB 	A	¶A4*	 	¶C4*	AO	¶AB6* ¶C6*	 DC¶C6*	 BN¶C4*	5* 	C¶CE¶C5*	AB¶C4*	 	¶C	8*NA¶CD 	A¶C	7* 	 P¶AB6* ¶CD B D B¶C	 	A	 ¶C	A	C¶C	CBC¶C4*	5* 	C¶C	5* 	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶C4*	AE	A¶HAD¶C	CBC¶C4*	C	 4*	¶C	 B¶C	8* B 	 ¶C4*	6* B ¶CGB¶AB BA¶ABC	A¶C	8* 	C	¶AB4* B¶CD 	AB¶CB 	¶ADA¶AD¶C4*QB¶C	AD ¶CD B 	AB ¶C	 G	¶ABN ¶C4*	C	 D ¶CD4* B¶C7*	A¶A4*	C¶C	8* 	AB¶A6*	¶C	 	AD¶C	 4*	A¶C	4* 	 ¶C4*E¶C	AB¶C4*	C	A	 	¶CD 4*	CB¶AB 	 ¶CE	¶C4*	5* 	C¶AB 4*R	C¶CB BA¶CDA	 B¶CD 5*	AB¶CBA¶C4*	 	7* ¶CD 4*	C	 ¶C4*	C	AB ¶AB4* B¶CD 5*	 B ¶A6*	¶CD6* ¶C4*E¶A5*	 	¶C4*E¶C4*	C	 D ¶CD BA4*	 ¶C	A	 B 	¶ABCB¶CD BNA	¶C4*	6* B ¶ABA	A¶C4*	C	AB ¶C	A	S 7*	A¶C	 G	¶CD D5* 	¶C	A	 	A¶AD 	 ¶C	4* 4*	 ¶AB6* ¶C	A	 B 	¶C	CBA¶C4*	C	AD¶CD BA5*T	 	¶C4*	AO	¶C	 	¶CB DA¶CD 9*	¶C	A	 4*	¶CBC¶C	8*NA¶C	C4*	A¶AD 	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶A4*	¶A5*	¶C	AB 	A¶CDAE¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	5* 	 ¶C	A	CB¶AB 	 ¶CD BNA	¶CBC	 ¶AB 	 B¶C	A	P¶C4*E¶C	8*NA¶C	6* 	A	C¶C	AB¶C	8* 	 D¶CD B 	AD¶CO	¶CD4* 	 ¶A5*	 	¶C	CBC¶ADC	¶C5*	 ¶C	8* 	A	 ¶A6*	¶H¶CF	¶A6*	 ¶CB BA¶C	6* 	A	C¶CD 8*	 ¶C	 	A	C¶C	A	 ¶AD 	 ¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	AD U¶AB D¶A4*	A¶CD 5*	AB¶C4*	CO¶C	7* 	 ¶C4*	ABAD¶CD 4*	CB¶AB BA¶AD ¶CK	A	 ¶C4*	C	 D ¶CD 4*	CB¶CB DA¶C	6* 	A	C¶AD ¶CD DAD ¶ABV¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶AB 	C¶ADC	¶A4*	A	¶C4*	C	 D ¶AB 4*	¶CD 8*	 ¶CB ¶C4*	AE	A¶CDA	 B¶CD 7*	 	¶HAD¶CD DA4*	¶AD D¶CD 4*	CB¶CFB¶CD 9*	¶CD DA4*	¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C	 	C	¶ADC	¶A4*	 	¶CD5* 	¶C	A	C¶CD 5*	 	A¶CD B D B¶AB B¶A4*	A	¶CD B 	AB ¶C5*	AB¶C	 BA	¶A4*E¶AF	¶A5*	 	¶CD D5* 	¶C4*	 B¶C	4* BC¶C	8* 	A	 ¶AD ¶CW¶AB4* ¶CDAB¶C	C4*	A¶AD 	¶C4*E¶C	A4*	¶CD 4*	4* 	¶CX¶ABCB¶CD B 6*	¶CD BA4*	 ¶CD6* ¶C4*	C	AD¶C	A	 ¶C	 BA	 ¶C	8* 	 D¶CW¶C4*	6* B ¶AB BA¶CK	A	 ¶C4*	6* B ¶A4*E¶AF¶C	8* B 	 ¶AB D ¶ABA	 	¶C4*	C	 D ¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	I¶CBC¶CD BNC¶C	4* 	 ¶HAD¶C	8* B 	 ¶AD¶CD 5*	A	 ¶AB 	A	¶C4*	 	7*Y4* BC¶C	4* 4*	 ¶A4*E¶L ¶C	 4*	 	¶C	8*Z¶C	¶C4*	C	A	 	¶C	8* 	AB¶C	I¶CX¶CD BNA	¶C	 	C	¶C	CBC¶ABC	 ¶A4*	A¶AD 	¶A4*	 	¶CB DA¶CB BA¶C	I¶C	 4*	A¶CD 5*	 	A¶CD 8*	 ¶AB 	 B¶CO	¶ABC	¶C	C4*	A¶AB¶C	 B6*N ¶C4*QB¶CD B 6*	¶C	8* 	C	¶C4*	¶CD 4*	5* ¶C4*	CO¶A4*	 B¶C	AB 	A¶C	8* 	4* ¶CD 	A¶C	 	AB ¶C4*	C	A	 	¶C	AE¶AD 	A¶C4*	L ¶ABA	¶AD ¶CBAB 	¶AB6* ¶C	ABN¶C6*	¶CDAB¶CD D6* ¶C5*	AB¶CD 8*	 ¶C4*	L ¶Ca	¶C4*QB¶ABC	A¶CK¶C	5* B¶C	8* 	AB¶C	CD 	¶ABC	 ¶CD4* 	 ¶CDAE¶ABA	 b	AB 	A¶AD D¶C4*	L ¶ABCB¶CD B 	4* 	¶AD D¶C	 	6* ¶CF	¶CD 7*	 	¶CBA¶C	 	AD ¶ABA	 ¶J¶C	4* 	 ¶C4*	4*I¶C	 	AB ¶C	8* 	4* ¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C	CBC¶C	4* 4*	 ¶C	C¶C	AB 	 ¶A4*	A¶C	A	 ¶CGB ¶C	5* D ¶J¶C	5* B¶ABCB¶CD B D 	 ¶CB¶C	AD ¶ADAB¶C4*	AB 	C¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	 	¶C5*	 ¶ABA	¶C4*	C	 D ¶AB 4*	¶C	A	 	A¶CK5*	¶C	5* B 	¶A4*	¶CD 5*	 D¶AB4* 	¶CD 9*	¶A5*	 	¶CB¶A6*	¶AB 	A	¶ADA	 ¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	5* D ¶C4*	4*I¶ADN¶CD 4*	4* 	P¶CD 5*	A	 ¶AB6* ¶C	C4*	A¶AB D ¶CD D5* 	¶C4*	 	¶CD B 5*	 ¶C	A4*	¶CD B 	4* 	¶C4*	AB 	A	¶CD BA4*	 ¶C	C4*	A¶CKDA¶C	A	 4*	¶C4*	AB 	C¶ADA	¶C	4* 	 ¶ADA	 ¶CD DA4*	¶ABA	A¶C4*	C	 D ¶CD4* 	 ¶C	8*Z¶C4*	AB 	C¶CD4* B¶C	C¶C	 	5* 	¶C	C¶C	4* 4*	 ¶C4*	AB 	C¶C4*	6* D¶CO	¶C	ABA¶CK	AB¶C4*	6* D¶ABC	 ¶AB4* B¶CD DAD ¶ABA	 	¶L¶C	 ¶C	ABN¶ADA¶CD B 	AD¶CD B 6*	¶CD B 	4* 	¶C4*	C	AB ¶C4*	¶C	ABNc D 4*	 ¶ABN¶C	 4*	 	¶CKDA¶H D¶C4*	6* D¶CX¶CD DAD ¶CB¶CD 5*	AB¶Jc6* ¶A6*	 ¶C4*	CG¶C	5* D ¶ADC¶C	CBA¶C	4* 	 ¶H 	¶CKDA¶AB BA¶A4*	A¶CD6* ¶C	5* B¶C4*	AO	¶C	CD 	¶Ca	¶A6*	¶CW¶L¶ABC	A¶C4*	CEB¶AB D ¶C4*Q	 ¶C	8* 	4* ¶AD B¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	A	¶ABA	 ¶C	4* ¶C	8* 	AB¶A7*	¶C4*	 B¶C	 4*	 	¶C4*	CEB¶C	 	A	C¶CD 5*	 D¶ADA	 ¶C	 BAB¶CKDA¶C	A	 B 	¶ABA	 	¶CK5*	¶AD B¶4* ¶C4*	AB 	C¶ABC	 ¶CD B 6*	¶CDA	 B¶CD6* ¶C4*	¶Ca	¶CB 	¶CD 5*E	¶C	 BA	¶AF¶H¶C	5* B¶ADA	 ¶A4*	c 8*	 ¶C	ABN¶C	 	5* 	¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶CE¶CD 5*	 B ¶A6*	¶C	CD 	¶CK¶CD B D 	 ¶H¶C7*	A¶C5*	ABdB¶CD BA5*	¶ABN¶C	AB¶C	I¶C4*	C	A	 	¶ABN ¶C	8* 	AB¶C4*	AB 	C¶CD ¶A4*	A¶A4*	¶CD B 	AB ¶CE¶A4*	 ¶A4*	¶ABA	 	¶AB5* 	¶C	 4*	A¶C	8* 	C	¶C	 	AB ¶ABA	 ¶C	C¶AB 	¶A7*	¶C	 	A	 ¶C	4* 	 ¶ABA	¶CK4*	 ¶CD BA4*	 ¶ABC	¶C4*	CEB¶C	A	 D ¶C	5* B¶AB 	 Be¶C4*	L ¶ADA	¶H 	¶CDAE¶C5*	AB¶C	C4*	A¶AD D¶C	 ¶HAD¶C4*	AO	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C4*	L ¶AB 4*	¶C	8* 	C	¶AD 	 ¶AB D ¶C	 BA	¶C7*	A¶CD B D B¶A5*	¶CB DA¶AB4* 	¶AD 	¶C4*	CO¶A4*E¶J¶C	 D¶C4*	6* D¶ABCB¶CD 5*	AB¶C	A	C¶C	CD 	¶C	8* 	A	 ¶ABC	¶C4*E¶C	 BAB¶C	AE¶CK5*	¶C	CBC¶CD D6* ¶C	 	A¶CD 9*	¶CD 	AB¶C	AB 	 ¶CGB ¶CD 7*	A¶CD DA4*	¶C	A	¶C	8* BC¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C4*	AO	¶C4*	C	AD¶CK4*	 ¶C	AB 	A¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C	4* 4*	 ¶CD4* 	 ¶C4*	CEB¶CW¶CD B 	AD¶CD B 	4* 	¶A4*	¶C4*E¶C	4* ¶ADA	¶ABC	¶C	 BAB¶C4*	L ¶CB ¶C	8* 	AB¶M 	fC	A¶ADN¶C4*	C	AD¶AB D ¶C	A¶C	 	5* 	¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶CD 4*	CB¶ABAD¶C	4* ¶CD 5*	 D¶CB 	 ¶CD5* 	¶CK¶C	 	AD ¶AB 	C¶A6*	 ¶AD 	 ¶COg	AB 	A	¶A5*	A¶AB 	C¶AB5* 	P¶C	A¶CD¶CBA	¶A6*	 ¶C4*	AB 	C¶C4*	 B¶C	 D¶C	A4*	¶C	AE¶A4*	A	¶CBA	¶ABA	 	¶CKDA¶ADC¶HAD¶CB ¶L¶AB4* 	¶CD B 5*	 ¶CB¶CD 	A¶ADAB¶C4*	5* 	C¶C	 B¶C4*	AB 	C¶C	A	 4*	¶C	A4*	¶ADA	 ¶CDAE¶C	C¶AB5* ¶C	7* 	 ¶C	 B¶C	8*NA¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶CD BA4*	 ¶C	8* 	 B ¶A4*	A	¶CD B 6*	¶AB 4*	¶C4*	ABAD¶ABCB¶AB D¶Ca	¶C	A	 D ¶C	 	A¶C	5* 	¶ABA	 	¶CGB¶C	8* BC¶C	 G	¶C	A	C¶ABA	 ¶4* ¶CD B D B¶H D¶Ca	¶CD¶AD B¶CD¶C4*	 	6* 	¶AB D ¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C	8* 	 B ¶CD 5*	 	A¶CGB¶AB 	¶C	5* 	¶C	ABA¶C	8* B 	 ¶C4*	¶C	A	 4*	¶CD 7*	A¶C4*	L ¶CK	AB¶C	 4*	 	¶CD 4*	CB¶C	A	 4*	¶CD B 	4* 	¶CDA	 B¶A6*	 ¶C	 BA	 ¶C	4* 4*	 ¶ABC	 ¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶A4*	A¶C	A	 B 	¶4* ¶C4*	C	AD¶C	 	AD ¶CDAB¶AB 	C¶CD 5*E	¶C	ABN¶ABA	A¶C	A	 ¶ADA	 ¶C	I¶C	 BA	¶C	5* B¶CD 9*	¶A4*	 B¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C4*	C	 4*	¶AB B¶C	 D¶C	 	A	C¶CGB ¶C	5* 	¶CD BNAb	5* 	¶CGB¶AD B¶C4*	AO	¶ADA	¶C	A	CB¶C6*	¶H 	¶C4*	AO	¶CD 	AB¶C4*	4*I¶C	CBC¶CD 7*	A¶C	8* 	 D¶C	8*NA¶CDAB¶C5*	 ¶C4*	6* D¶C	8*NA¶CD BNA	¶ABC	A¶CGB¶CD 5*	ABhC4*	A¶C	 	A	 ¶ABN¶CB DA¶C	 B6*N ¶C	A	CB¶C	 BA	 ¶CX¶CD 4*	5* ¶CD B 	AD¶C	A	 	A¶AB¶C4*	AB 	C¶C4*QB¶CD 4*	¶CBA¶C4*	C	AB ¶C	8* 	C	¶CD B D B¶J¶ADAB¶C	 BA	 ¶CD 5*	 	A¶C	A	¶C4*	5* 	A	¶C	A	 ¶AB6* ¶AB4* B¶C	 G	¶C	C4*	Ai4*	CB¶C4*	AE	A¶C4*	 	¶CD B 	5* ¶C4*	 	6* 	¶CD BNA	¶C4*QB¶C	 	A	C¶C	 	AD j¶A6*	 P¶C	A¶CBAB 	¶C4*Q	 ¶C4*	¶AB 	 B¶CD D5* 	¶C4*	AB 	C¶A6*	 ¶C	8* 	4* ¶ABC	 ¶C4*	5* 	A	¶CD 8*	 ¶C4*	 	6* 	¶AD D¶C	AB¶A5*	 	¶C	8* B 	 ¶CBA¶CDAB¶CK	AB¶C	ABN¶C4*	6* B ¶C	 	AD ¶C	 G	¶CBC	 ¶C	 	C	¶C	ADA	¶C4*	C	A	 	¶CB k	CBA¶C	8* 	4* ¶AD 	 ¶C4*	C	 D ¶CD B 	4* 	¶C	8* 	A	 ¶CB 	l	¶C	CBA¶C	 	AB ¶CB¶C	C4*	A¶CD 5*E	¶C	4* ¶CW¶AB 4*	¶CB DAmB¶CE¶C4*	AO	¶AB BA¶C	8* 	4* ¶C4*	 	¶C	C¶ADA	 ¶CD B 	5* ¶CD BA5*	¶ADC	¶CB¶C	 BA	 ¶ABC	 ¶AB5* ¶AB 	A¶C4*	CO¶CD B 5*	 ¶C	 	5* 	¶C4*	C	A	 	¶ABA	 ¶CD4* 	 ¶C	 BA	¶ABAD¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶Ak4*	AB 	C¶ABC	¶AB D ¶C	8* BA	¶AB D ¶AB Bn¶C	4* 	 ¶C4*	AB 	C¶C	 	A	 ¶AB BA¶AB D ¶ABA¶A4*	A	¶CBA¶C	 D¶CD 5*	 D¶CD BNA	¶CDAB¶AF	¶CK4*	 ¶H 	¶C4*	C	 4*	¶H D¶C	CBC¶AB B¶C	A	 B 	¶CDAE¶CD 5*	AB¶C	5* 	¶C	A¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C	 	AD¶C4*	 	¶C6*	¶J¶A5*	 	¶CD B D B¶AF¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	 	A	C¶C	 	AB ¶ABC	 ¶C	A	C¶AB 	A	¶CD B D B¶C4*	 	A	C	¶CO	¶C6*	¶CB ¶AF	¶AB D ¶CD 4*	C	 ¶CB¶L¶ADA	¶CD BNA	¶CD ¶L ¶A4*	¶CD D5* 	¶C5*	 ¶Ca	¶AB 	C¶L ¶CD 5*	 B ¶CD BNA	¶C4*	AE	A¶ABC	A¶C	8* 	AB¶AB BA¶ADA¶CD D5* 	¶CBAB 	¶C	 	AB ¶ABC	 ¶ABA¶C	ABA¶CD 5*	 	A¶ADC¶C	8*NA¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	C4*	A¶AB5* ¶C4*	C	A	 	¶L¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶C	A	oC¶CK	A	 ¶CD B 5*	 ¶CD 9*	¶C4*	ABAD¶C	4* BC¶C4*	C	AD¶CD 5*E	¶C	4* BC¶AD ¶CD 5*	A	 ¶ABC	¶C	8* BA	¶CD 4*	¶HAD¶CK4*	 ¶H D¶AB 	A¶C	 ¶AB4* 	¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C	 ¶C4*	CEB¶A5*	 ¶CB 	¶CD B D B¶CD D6* ¶AD D¶J¶C	 	5* 	¶CD 7*	 	¶AB 	 ¶C	A	 	A¶A4*	 	¶C	CD 	¶CD BNC¶CD 8*	 ¶CD 5*	A	 ¶C	AE¶CD 8*	 ¶C4*	5* 	A	¶A4*	A¶C4*Q	 ¶AB 	 ¶C4*	5* 	C¶AB 	A¶AB 	C¶C4*	L ¶CD 7*	A¶ABC	¶CB ¶CK¶CDAB¶C4*	C	A	 	¶AB 	 B¶CD BNC¶C7*	A¶A5*	A¶AB¶C	8* B 	 ¶CW¶CDAE¶CD B D 	 ¶C	 D¶A5*	 ¶C	 B ¶C	5* B 	¶AB B¶AB 	C¶CD4* B¶A4*E¶AB 	C¶C	6* ¶AB¶C4*	C	 D ¶ABA	¶CD 	AB¶AD D¶C4*	C	AB ¶C	 ¶C4*	 	¶ADA¶CGB¶C4*	ABAD¶C5*	 ¶C4*	ABAD¶C	 	C	¶CD B D B¶CK¶HAD¶CDAB¶C6*	¶C	8* B 	 ¶ABN ¶C	AB¶AD¶CBA¶CO	¶C	 BAB¶ADC¶C4*	CG¶C	 D¶ABA	A¶CD4* B¶CBC	 ¶H 	¶ABA	A¶CD 7*	A¶C	8* 	AB¶C4*	 	7* ¶C4*	CEB¶CD 4*	¶AB5* ¶C4*	CG¶C	ABA¶C4*bD 7*	 	¶CB BA¶C	AB¶C	 B¶CD B 	AD¶C	AB¶C4*	6* B ¶C	5* B 	¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C4*	 	6* 	¶CBA	¶CD DA4*	¶C	8*NA¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C	CBA¶CD 4*	¶CKDA¶C	8* 	C	¶CD DAD ¶AD 	 ¶C	CB 	¶C	ADA	¶AB4* 	¶C	CD 	¶L¶C	8*NA¶CBA	¶CF	¶C	Ip¶ABA¶A5*	¶C4*	CO¶CD 8*	 ¶CD 	A¶C	A	 ¶AB D¶C	6* 	A	C¶C	5* B 	¶A4*	 	¶CD ¶C4*	AB 	C¶A4*	A¶A4*	¶ABC	¶AD 	A¶C4*	 	7* ¶CD 5*	 D¶CD 7*	 	¶ABAD¶C	 BA	 ¶C	8* 	4* ¶CO	¶C4*	C	A	 	¶CK	AB¶CB 	 ¶C4*	L ¶AD4* ¶C	5* B¶C	8*Z¶CBC	 ¶CD 8*	 ¶C	4* ¶AD ¶CD 7*	A¶C4*	 	A	C	¶CD 	A¶A4*	 B¶AB 	 B¶C	8* 	C	¶C	4* BCq	 	A¶CD 7*	A¶C	 	¶CD 5*	 	A¶CB DA¶A4*	 	¶CD B 	5* ¶CD BNC¶CD 5*	AB¶C	8*Z¶CD ¶ADA	 ¶C	AB¶C	4* ¶CB BAP¶C	AB 	A¶CD 7*	 	¶CO	¶C	AB 	 ¶CD B 5*	 ¶CGB ¶A4*	 	¶AB 	¶C4*	L ¶C	 	AD¶ABA	A¶A6*	 ¶C	 	C	¶ABA	¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C	CD 	¶CD6* ¶C	8* BC¶C4*	 B¶H D¶C	 	C	¶CD4* B¶A4*	 B¶C	8* B 	 ¶C4*	6* B ¶A5*	 ¶ADA	¶CD DAD ¶C	A	¶CD D5* 	¶C	 BAB¶CW¶CD 4*	5* ¶CD 5*	 B ¶C	4* 	 ¶C	CBA¶C	AB 	 ¶C	AE¶AB 	C¶AD D¶C	A	¶C	6* ¶A4*E¶C	 	AB ¶C	I¶ABA	A¶CK	A	 ¶A4*	C¶C	AB¶C	¶C4*	C	 4*	¶L ¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶C4*	5* 	A	¶C	 	A	 ¶H 	¶CD 	A¶CD DAD ¶CB 	¶CD B 	5* ¶AD 	 ¶CF	¶C4*E¶C	A	 B 	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶AB ¶C	ArB 	¶C	5* B 	¶C	8* 	C	¶C	 B6*N ¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶CD4* B¶H D¶J¶C	ABN¶AD ¶AB D¶AB4* B¶CD BA4*	 ¶C4*Q	 ¶CB¶C4*	C	AD¶CD 7*	A¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C	A	¶C4*E¶C	A¶AB B¶C5*	 ¶ADAB¶C	A	 B 	¶C4*	C	AD¶CD 5*	 B ¶C4*	ABAD¶CD4* B¶C4*	5* 	A	¶MA¶C	 BA	¶CD 	A¶AB 4*	¶C	 ¶ABC	A¶CK	AB¶C	8* s	 	AD¶C4*	C	 4*	¶ABA¶C	4* 	 ¶C	I¶C4*	 	A	C	¶ABC	¶C	6* ¶C	A	¶C4*	AB 	C¶C	 B6*N ¶C	6* 	A	C¶A6*	 ¶C	 BA	 ¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C	 D¶CBA¶C4*	CEB¶CBC	 ¶AD B¶C	6* ¶C	A	 4*	¶CD BA4*	 ¶C	4* ¶C	A	C¶CE	¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C	 	A	C¶ABC	 ¶H 	¶CD5* 	¶CBA	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶CD 9*	¶A4*	A¶C	8* 	4* ¶C	 B6*N ¶AD B ¶C4*	AO	¶AB 	A¶C4*	AB 	A	¶CD DA4*	¶C	A	 D ¶J¶CD 7*	A¶CO	¶AD D¶C	 	AD¶C	 B6*N ¶CD DA4*	¶C	A¶CB BA¶ABN¶AD ¶C4*Q	 ¶C	8* 	 B ¶C4*QB¶A4*	 B¶C4*	AB 	A	¶C4*	ABAD¶C4*	5* 	A	¶C	6* 	A	C¶C	A	 4*	¶CD DA4*	¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C4*QB¶C4*	AB 	A	¶AD4* ¶AB 	¶CD D5* 	¶CB BA¶CBA	¶C4*	ABAD¶CD 	AB¶C	 	A	C¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶A7*	¶C	8* 	C	¶CK¶CD 5*	AB¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶C	 BA	¶A5*	 	¶C	ADA	¶AD B ¶C	A	 4*	¶CF	¶CK5*	¶C4*	C	AB ¶C	 ¶ABA¶C4*	C	A	 	¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C	A4*	¶C	5* B 	¶C	AB 	 ¶ABN¶C4*	C	A	 	¶C	4* 4*	 ¶C5*	AB¶ADAB¶C4*	C	AD¶AD 	¶CD 7*	 	¶C	8* B 	 ¶CW¶C	4* 4*	 ¶CD 5*	AB¶A4*	¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶C	8* 	4* ¶CD 4*	CB¶C	5* D ¶C	8* 	4* ¶C4*QB¶CD B 6*	¶C	 D¶AB 	A¶CB DA¶C	 4*	A¶CD4* B¶CB 	¶C7*	A¶CD BNA	¶C	 	AB ¶CDAB¶C4*	 	6* 	¶AD B ¶C4*	C	 4*	¶ABA	 	¶CD 4*	C	 ¶C4*	AE	A¶C4*	5* 	C¶ABA¶CGB¶CD 	A¶C	8*NA¶CD B 5*	 ¶A4*	 B¶C	8* 	 B ¶C	 	¶ABA	 ¶ABN ¶CD B 	AD¶CD4* 	 ¶C	CD 	¶C	8* 	 B ¶C4*	¶CBC	 ¶CD 5*	 	A¶CD 8*	 ¶CBC¶A4*	 B¶CD DAD ¶C5*	AB¶CD 7*	A¶A7*	¶C	5* 	¶CB BA¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C	AE¶C	CBA¶C	8* 	AB¶AB 	A	¶C4*	 	A	4* ¶ABC	A¶C4*	 	6* 	t¶CW¶C4*	ABAD¶AB 4*	¶C	 BA	¶C4*	AO	¶C4*	6* B ¶CD B 	5* ¶C5*	AB¶C	6* 	A	C¶ADN¶A4*	C¶CD B 	4* 	¶C	 	6* ¶AB BA¶C4*	C	AB ¶C	 B ¶CD B 6*	¶C4*	CG¶A5*	A¶CBA	¶CD D5* 	¶CK	AB¶C	 D¶AD 	A¶C	 G	c B D B¶C4*	 	A	C	¶C4*	6* B ¶A5*	A¶CD 5*	 	A¶C4*QB¶ABCB¶Ca	¶C4*	C	 D ¶C	8* 	4* ¶C	5* B 	¶C	I¶C	 Bu8* BA	¶C	5* D ¶ADAB¶M 	¶C	4* 4*	 ¶C	 G	¶AB 	Ab4*	C	 4*	¶ABCB¶C	 	6* ¶CD4* B¶C4*	6* D¶C	8* B 	 ¶CB 	¶CD B 	AB ¶CD B 	4* 	¶C	 ¶CD 4*	4* 	¶C5*	 ¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶ADC	¶C	 4*	A¶ABC	¶AB 	Cv5* 	A	¶AB D ¶C4*	C	AB ¶CD B 6*	¶A4*	 	¶CD 7*	 	¶CE¶ABC	A¶C4*	AO	¶A4*E¶CD4* B¶AD D¶C4*E¶C4*	AB 	C¶C	 BAB¶C	C4*	A¶C	7* 	 ¶CF	¶CD 4*	¶CD 5*	 	A¶L ¶C5*	 ¶C	ABN¶A7*	¶C	 BA	 ¶C	5* 	 ¶ADAB¶C	 	C	¶A6*	¶AB4* ¶CD 5*E	¶C4*	6* B ¶AB ¶C	4* 4*	 ¶ABC	 ¶CD BNC¶C6*	¶CD 5*	 B ¶C	CD 	¶CB 	 ¶CBA¶C6*	¶ADA	¶MA¶A4*	 	¶ADN¶C	 ¶C	6* ¶C	 ¶A4*	A	¶C	A4*	¶CBAB 	¶AB 	 B¶CD5* 	¶CD B 	5* ¶C	CBC¶CD4* 	 ¶CK4*	 ¶AB 	C¶C	5* B 	w	 	¶C4*	 	A	C	¶ABN ¶A5*	A¶CF	¶CD DA4*	¶CBC¶C	CB 	¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C4*	4*I¶A4*	A¶C	ABN¶AB6* ¶AB D ¶CD P¶CD 5*	 D¶CD DA4*	¶C	 	AD¶C4*E¶ABA	¶C4*	5* 	A	¶ABA	¶AD D¶C	AE¶AB5* 	¶C	8* 	C	¶C5*	 ¶A4*	 	¶A4*	 B¶C	C4*	A¶C	A	 4*	¶CD DA4*	¶4* ¶ABA	 	¶C	 	AB ¶AB B¶CX¶C	5* 	 ¶CD4* B¶M 	¶C	5* Bx	 	¶C	4* BC¶CDAB¶AB6* ¶CDAB¶C	5* 	 ¶CO	¶C4*E¶AB 	C¶C	8*Z¶A5*	 	¶ABC	¶C	 D¶C	 	¶AB6* ¶A5*	 ¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC¶CO	¶A5*	 	¶CX¶C	A¶C4*	¶C	6* 	A	C¶C	5* D ¶C4*	4* B 	 ¶CD BA4*	 ¶C	A4*	¶ABN¶C	8* 	A	 ¶C4*	6* B ¶A4*	C¶AB5* ¶C4*	CG¶C	8* BA	¶C	 	A¶CB¶AD¶C4*	 	¶CD 4*	CB¶ADAB¶C	 4*	 	¶CD B 6*	¶C4*	 	7* ¶C	A	C¶C5*	 ¶A5*	 	¶C	A	 B 	¶CB DA¶AB4* ¶C4*	 	6* 	¶C4*	AB 	A	¶J¶C	AB¶CD4* 	 ¶A5*	A¶ADA	 ¶CD 4*	5* ¶CB BA¶J¶CD BA4*	 ¶A5*	 ¶C6*	 DC¶AB 	A	¶CED¶ADC¶CBAB 	¶C	CBA¶C	CB 	¶C	A	 4*	¶C	 	5* 	¶CKDA¶C	A	 ¶C4*	6* D¶CFB¶ABCB¶CBAB 	¶C	 	AB ¶CD DA4*	¶A6*	¶C	A	 ¶CD B 	5* ¶C4*	C	 4*	¶CD 	A¶CB 	¶C	 	A	C¶ABA	¶ABN¶C4*	CEB¶C4*	AB 	C¶C	 	AD¶AB D¶MA¶A4*	A	¶C4*Q	 ¶HAD¶CD 5*	 	A¶C	 ¶CW¶C	8* 	AB¶C	6* ¶H D¶C4*	C	 4*	¶ABC	¶ADA	 ¶HAD¶C	8* B 	 ¶H¶C4*	CO¶AB4* 	¶CK¶L ¶CD DA4*	¶C	ADA	¶CB¶L¶CD 9*	¶ADC¶CD 4*	¶CBA	¶CGB ¶CD 7*	A¶CBA¶ABC	 ¶AF	¶CD BA5*	¶C	AD ¶C	CD 	¶C	 	AB ¶C6*	 DC¶AB4* 	 ¶ABC	Ah4* ¶C	 	¶CD ¶C	AB¶AD B ¶C	4* ¶H¶C	 B¶4* ¶C	4* ¶C4*	¶AD B v¶C	¶AB¶C	 B¶CD ¶CBAyA¶CBA	A¶	C	¶A¶ y";s/\w/$h{$&}||$&/ge while$G++<10;print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVtrj1tFEv3c@ytaKMvdvVyJRbI9WbF86L7tsTOeeDK8EtBKqyQEEggQwiOgZf9WfkD@WPZ21@tUO6Aotsf31Y@qU6dOlZ89ev50/fr1Xx9/8LdvpiGnVy/n9jJMn0zDq5eppECvw/SofjGH1I7Xt2E6TkMMcTn2go7N7WWYPl2@L7GdFvTDMD1pZ7W/Sxymz@nqev3H0xDatYHvcGs5lmMepg/bkZQjvQ7TV3TqaqTXYfp@GuZ6bDUu96of/F/D9CvNJLaXYfq6/XlWr6@vw3R7ucFyu/p/mIZvh3a83oDfhukhDbz@H6b701Bi/TdM58uSxTqon6chBZlwfRumx7Qk9McDnl9b2eHHoV7XTuS3YfqSnkojPtAjhulyWtY5T8MPAy9@exmmZzylHPltmJ7TDSIv02fLAtaTeTT3lgGk@m@YnrYTl8kmfhum79rd6@ecin0aprJcFuqq/NYG8OrlMP3Em7iu59inYdou5y6zGaZf5G70OkzzMpa4HLg7LZNJ0x0aadumZebXy3Vtz/fLPoQ62FTPH6YdjXmYvuCp0Ya2Z1xMc57zlOv4humKHl0PfETzJiMb/v7@jf988NZf1Bzm7TK9dF5HtqXRzbu2Sm1li5y142Uk0705Rn72cn5c5ryPzRTqt2u1kroWYXmv59SPZ3wvWaMtL0dshhBzc6w8q9XQeoVb9WXdnigbEcNMo2nO2Q5c1C829dl@16Ku@iyfF0Mi22@zPpTE46x3SDQUumJ5aHvQhiYg113yifsYeF1TbrNerixscTPNg5aZ9yjzglaTLjj1ZdjLfOdmuDx72i1Z/Tbl1GCHZlroZjyg9qHN7Xbya7ce@cQzflaeZf9SEGfQPQx8LDQvWu6z7VGkbvFxJi@VTVuOtcXrn9LcoG3RFnGP11VQNPJtsmwSLV81pfXIz6UpLEdpMXmzFs/g55QNPz@ndZt329hdpse2y9sup2xTpP1eyxbQOp6NhCfNigPvaxDzbl/Sg8jRyXR02rJJ61ENOzF@y/42@2ITbisgNlC/uwpmw9Xkyswf8tHZY1tPARs1opvjMfHY1Nnu2A3rgpLVtMGwj822jHB/nv1MK86AXEe4rffeN@O1q9SvyMINHOrBzUi2tGs4HnMiF0@yDXMAsJB1pdDWdoz85DqDU9S7k5GEuGuXH6OORP0m63bWNRarb/ev/szr0GYSV7zt4m6rkSzWbDKwq9e/siLvLAgmQJGXEz4M5B9tq6uBZxccxAJi3SG9Z4jO/GFFqoW2r2jQRSBuC9ZL48UFWJ4uqFtHQNbJfpSPKbjNWawyJO9@y1UfRfWGHaMmm0VbjgRopRgvxqYPrWZity7qpB97q58ZNiI71D/H4HBMUKtZeKMl/PjOSAkE2QEFNJdNOMUxhLm1oqzbXF0pgXKG8OW0O2YkMijFcLYbeoBGxTb3NlUBdcOeNr1UGlKsedearQbd9z2DmoQiNi94aok3@VIbR4iwSYjrJX4i8ZNpD1ho3asrjNcWT9EBcmIKOR8YT5wB8omypy7GYQzOnxpWcgwmX2rr0UYX3L2bkwWccXbwBD7HuLznsXOMXJ7r5jKfZzA6PQ1hui5qG44OivDAHMICHq8mo21dKJgGgJcstxAfcunzAJZhLschurma2a9s8PL3XSXoy/zzm7yEIE2WzoLpPYSGyChj@KGAIw4cLGaDYRUag0MVslGwDjnCU/VMMvPuJoWG2RiDRdJbRi@IiQhqc1iyGxa1anHfFAx7P9OVNPRq47qMEhMkrn7OeQqGAg0mNKJ7iBdsLOLYDB@4HWpB7B3izrcwHDlzujk6DLpiqowbzca0GTkcXvs91XA7gw2sdXOvjMwbchpTUl4h5usWowEsn7EcuOSNFOPMkqxKdGiEhk2NUya2M8uh2Ln5dvP9oJMSAnEAhgv7MZcIiYRyaI4Cy5AfGJ2OBUesXsC@wceXSdLgzoNnubIgariNnCOPWD7ewlWDBW0msBkhBLhkaZZ9MNsR19tp2CryRFoFmEGxVIvHVwTcGWB7gqrBh3buTYgrgX8@rC29EHtGxi9pj6CqIpqyLyXAJZ2EJ56YLl8qR8SsO51fs1GpG0gEQuwMLqUAHNS9dnCP/InvK3ligoxSQ1UKsO0yJQs4yK9il9kRvMC2CHklC5BMhP80A/EbuayBEgzWow4azelggow0uwhMXnyp2khzz1SS4y4uOOCizQYIfPHDWJQPHh2YtjXci9PxoO9hJuvI8sXDtrdCelSbYANJZTaGqWHAHiQkRfCUDYURw7gnAUZDGGbZdznJn3XfttlMa0Gh4J2Z83HnUSkoKGjCqhnI2eiieoQ0sD3KWJz5VJcsmz0yuDIYk2/SiFZj7CSTWaitbKaQJQ3zgrU5BtRphKacExkVxKFB1SV@qARUdl1NV7mKI3otjT1JcGQ3Dg7I9pacN9v4ImO@zw@0cAzBibNDiw/oatHJfp6fbTkgalaR5YYyLc0bNbIKzuu@zyrUnmnOqRYBYHsQtqXAw9HdDEJ1Y8H6ipePIHw1FGJNKqFEAFSwsJPvVdS8Okn0/XZdugCgKXtB0ibGIVtk7JfiBLEc1cI0b2PSseUg5nFBg5lOQ@SK0lmVLtUW3KNxEg1UnVKktEo4vzwhg9pJkT65nICzgZsnLNytJTPlg6bgkoh2GpZsOvAF2uy7J9ArjERiz9Y0y5KADJqSdqmpkdr@7Ri@nMkSjjhS3UYnfnlnhdSPiLZ8LSKfZM188cFxI9RRJSO9@spksLXEbvKYNYd5WrVGtYKLA8hhstpO0F3aQs6Vk4NHkpVm8YEsgq4yFmUJWWmvkSeVyGKHJSC6SpqZjHfOOi9MrFUwO6beCZGBKDVyaaTQKGAjSd2GtfH7wSEHU3jRNnlFdtmZNKk9qleivMtevbd7F9OiPaU1GgYmbxwPchtWBgPojlJRc0qiW2N1TTH0gyTTxvYkvcerjLlw4BObsnQWxCyQ8LWMBlS8DXrVp8dRdMqU1aIhjBK5YkYoGTw/@hZAqUn3xKDF0nFBQXwlnUH8QMiDZQpBEtQH8ldb9@KokBBZ1sxJefJCXbEoyqmNQOsZBMNYUJFuF6xHUAHcYU6bhW3tAPUfC/kOCvVH0JQ02ZUR6y7e8wmuYalqlyfJ0LWuLqi0M@Ztc0AvuFBY0KeCVavWILWO2aUrVh9jd2tjeSIma2IWJi@WrWviCGrutaONZIZfs4ErlnImrhRWbEdsC3ImD9pIdrPK1To5TNcVAphupIxip/l0NuM4aPw9@rKBehOvk1QHhW@xxaIYkeM3khIgPz9VKA0LIIwvXz4F3VoTd@RR4M3k/XcBiKttfputmspVndiNyOo2M2aMusnGbUkXRjtTYFqLXppAtsU0F0O5EeLkWYdWXoUTmpz@jU8dugpwCiDbxfxdJ31oZFTf5fKPCH0uRit4GaNQ4yYoPQeivO/xjyt0rLiJTs9FCArBwCQ1zpzKvK4y2xDwwimywmzP/6DEBznADFU2lBbiabZ4pU9rhIRkYAyhszCSS4VpW55IqqXmMOLFbAb3gwaiy@hyLlcNIsRx1bmEUn9y9xYk6aZrvTAODzlVl2IJiD0q26zHTla8PElMUvh@BkUZLF2YvJUqVCnH0hO4bYZShGlJc3DlcQ4He6Tze67xc1wC6ugtCYUDIZTehjQfIaS8cB7rqsoRI5chR9EY4CpANiHOghCdtfa@EgJ1rcpyX8wETq5ESwI9r1XbxIMCucMZjSo0Pr5uDWq1BYO74KaqXpLuoWCmZEZan5BgcV8FlRYEeTjWdmpmAiJjErCGekBnMvpddpa1HruqWOipQV0QLjolJVKu1sGsRTpBmrdcQQJH/mLNOMU4o@iD5G/7CAKjJ2HWHnA2uuyyCGU0l9uZ067GByBxR/FnTVeQS@UuWvddOlZw2Qhq@Bob5D6GpMwMOKCyzgUErEjnGmssOQIXUG9k97iEp9DTz6mO9ExikLZrcPhUL0KKTvkUVnlR@9ZGICROKCxx9LQSiZX/Ldqpw7NVYYGNSMNVT3YO2jCBck1ZOaWTNWbV/kSnE2rU5VO6EcXwJmP92@SuhqM/qJpi7TOeDLP@8wYua9ilsZkGWzAvStm4VrXIO15UEWO9CqjhQHTYSfIctXFS8YxDPruQpYPcmXJiwYq6G5V084xNVA4RFJX@pDeGAU6jOivhQhe0yMzSzt0@tdFgruRLyKuFji3U1ZmVBwNIUc4EAW8ZpHCs1R4a2grPvS7jG3qFLO9h@ifdcqqoFR8SuXGQvfoci9bBUGUF9eJ27LlJB9DdJWKY5Id/oEDz/uw1/HLpQz0eqiWqx0julDtygR600cYAmIYyU93w3E8PmApvKjRfrEZsTEza7hctoqFWG6FSaj0pPwLHNfHAtT@JhC5AILRIe3t6fq/LbE0evaziuVHBFHtr0Yz1CHuSCTeqhq1G6F3bdumbNdrNYHNrDD6dzKbqSpef6ay4pxhzuZO8wQnEWpVVk7hytWRBd140vFYjrtmhrzbJUK4RVbpga4mc@SB2J2Eb7Grs8Y2FBOxRLNqX4zOAmBOuqvYICVvgJzqvPet6EQ5965E5p@Sl0KPJLQXZW8e5lb16IpdAyAFdUChCWo0deGhP9bHvcTC9nkebkPIWrWtYPOroLSr@MmPbgK7@0onuVhR3EkLf4oGpiYpkIloIb4y@UqM9K9x4axuhMo41fERXCuuaF02y0hQCBD1xMBH9pL0XY2NQ1Ud1CubKUA2xKFd6WVm6BXs1zlrFZielchCyphPOUc5GlKNRvMG0CmUmEXtTOGlnm31Y@Mk6pUSxt/7ZFLpSklBr4EzKlKCl7mgh2glbUVKgeKJo2n036jk7zc@MqUs9R7y6GI@totzDN@oZnt103UzaxZOtr0d1OYRgc0tWxn@2xnXtAeDCVtc@w53BywMfOMNlIY0jDIRUU6Wj/RDFV4T9ynZYIr0zrlhQZiwUq4QW5l80DdeeAtf6vhl9ZiGQsnUGRfGI6IX@sIDz2e1JkHa1YCtCnYPQAbt0GaEblcLR2RhcXrLWfpcMlJnrUlYe3Pbdxm8ss2gqsIGBZPRzlI03o5YrbkNqQXXNEIFDYNlM8F770UShsAKJOJmUNQRsDittwIPs70WIoedKRzD6cx9n8wz5qg@63Omk1SWqEonzco52p0sYlTgopdtizmI2llCO32IPgwZiQGMsN5m9nPIG@clM6ITAduE994MJMs7bRtV/tahKC00AusEOVrn6KtjcorTyf27MQGvfxWLHZoTMyrd@XyGpuAcy8GmCX@Kf1WUltT@eZBjW6Ip1XxVa4Oc3hLXdD4Ks1l5OqpoA16Ih8IB5skaXJK@A9otTu5OgdaHZHTaoJyxOaM5J0eTC96swVsgPVzQYtt@XNTlLJWOOmyrc2A9IJORac5ND53OLG73@DO12m9HqbV3hDH4DxiSp@3lOQO63zaeVjCKp4e3k2tOvra0Gy4BK/qw/tZnmPp7kYLM1DfS9zHvolxF966BqvuUPJCFQlUBzmzK7wmY47W@RX@Xob@Lsl1RSfhOuJatt22y@FdJjYe6qh4nImi1324uUyCevrPOsnfgLKQxOcmyD/I15yfJGWPvqZfztrfd/fPffL9698fi/N97@3@@/33j73a8exRePnzx9dGP3zjv/eu8f7z97/uS7n16//j8)

[Generated using this.](https://tio.run/##jVxdjxvHEXzu@xXtCyPp5qSjZHNJWeeLZMBAkCfDechDTMc4J4JlQJZPOhmCIss/Kz8gPywKP5a7XdXVe0KUhDySu7MzPd3V1dVz9fTV8@7Dhz98crV54ffuXx0dPXl@cefLs7O/3708O/v33e/v/vjq6dUn82/Xb9btu/ndny@v/J/PXt397LOzswefLk/Oj67nd85O1g9O57O3F7Nn72a33v/22@z5t7N7p6ffne//cDF7O//x6fX50ZtnPz1/eufO7N4XT56f@K1bvv3x6cf9@sTfvT86@vX6qX91@fry0aOvfv15M@jzo1l8@@jRX1786@mL1xf3Nx98fbH/4/qPz3bvfr9@sr5utzd3fHxy2y/@5P3Lx09mlxezB@ezHy5mn57PXl7c2bz6ff6P9ZvT2fzWrdkPn/w@//blz9dvv5ufPD4@frT79Pb88e3j24@Obx@fz77Z/OIy/uKSf3GJvzievZz9MHt5d/bN7HL2zfGT3eTsRri5xuxvX/71gV/4@t1v6/fns/n8x/Ojo9n3Fy9fvts8yeZWX5@crzfvj2ffH59fz9frN/P1ZqbWu7nb/O9msnw30evZn09Pv3hw//zq1U8vXr8///DhyN1s0dz8v//xzevtf8y2r812/4Y/714smu3ebv8Nn/Sv8Dq7f/t3uysdPnjYdu9377ZXs8MdfLz17uvbf13rL7C9cv/R5uX2d/s3q/GO4y@7tnuMYcDDM2yH1A/IYaSbb43fOVypa@ME7J57N24Pj9Tf0cNE2TAUs2Vz@PHwk@0fDrc8zOgwhH62himDdeg/3H1hmI7DIw2PcLjw9gn6AS@HKRPXH0Y8XMM93nL/Yb8YYCHhocNKHYYdFmVYwDgH/afL1ttLfwmLazPehMxrsLwwGXH2493xice/4CLs/lcYRdfipVYNFjta9WBp4xNantDtd8e5GzdXeMBw5X75PfwFDXrz10Xz6eEdNoXRdrZ@NR0tZpjB4BYGKwk@AKZzd4dxd40Ttvn@wSgGc93PCD3lsGH6C26vODzy@NQ@DsUOF9K7w2DO@1t3LV7q8AyrsPa7WRhsXvqnLvgdiwPKGzSuyWi0XbC8w1OMDjW4GWf/Y4PnDJ/44PHGWVy2fhzxbXSMwT2MJtE1XGkwWodnJhdscdSOYzmYcdiVbuiDXRkGj3JYj96oMDBZHOOwwPqyzn4/h6ftx8uGW9VjcAzmHh2BDztoAZ4jmknYY@wV0aaT24KddxjU6HHxAdl9Ghr7/mtx5PtvLFtcpGEowUGOvnhvweNgGSeAI/A4gQFyiMW2YXkMdo8HlzDOCwQbMGLYQ1tr5fG49Gq8eHv/6TA7GOKN3EuYGLUc3gcg8MQRn1gKAJat0gIWy47Zo5cCdyTs5@C4os@DIGueEFjY4fEBhu3G4zLt34P3c688W7Al8q@fNxNhm0w7OobBkC0ivAVC0@imAXAMBjcRtjHIdwSM8yZIqwygyiOSMO1sYSPiEyPAin6oH6Yl/zLu/7CDhweFGBrHMq5k1wwdC24dd0@xPWDUsLl58JtPHjbyf2Tu0VgT2rLxOxHoIKoPno7cybCVPecgCegrrxcsDyGDT3qLeBnaARk/T2QSEvlF37J7M2YVYm33jymHapjIPAwrWoTp5LtXaFvsNUbUbmblRB/MyrKPkNjf4s6LERweergCukhG2V5gnuFFmMAc0yF2jVnFuLvDjumaFb47Jh97v@ZiO1pM4UbLjPlETGG02wyuLa49wP7IGYjotmxWhEXKognSYXri0qdhIILIabhUtAfHr/LcZ6hohvl0sT0k3LeIVMqsD5JfmAYcB4OgsI9NwCBXJhICPDx68KM5NejfFfAvokt8aKSTchxkdACBbxwk2mXcrUgQAFHiCtqKbfywqUgcci4YYhjOcKdlEyRatQtiEsF7qqPtoLm0CFZC7ouZW/Q6ecUiwjHnRBTwp3IlluHhaCVxv1PqfPgBQvgQSngEkHPrLApTNAiDgdshEw3WBHwh8FAIBJ22QaKpIM2jWWTAPxJpQNyMGTXSgsj7QPYWRsc0GSVyPQK2bB9gRTtbWza1K4mfBcjJuzUxALgqarRdgyW1FGiRDGa4p8lc6ZUBxNpHAR5nimTvSRKbHHd0oOUsxMsRsMQQHxB08Ogmgp@YR1peM@PkPFC3LmhIiCdhX0d/l9AnAhJFFzJuiLYvwJlInMl5E/8Wc8JM448XDlkc5s2IOXO6XVDUEBaTyQEfE1k4YBzzjlK2uwMqImFzDXAs/y4x@DZRKxiNxIDvBhdvlkI655nLyUWn4CSCCOcFCwjSGaco03DwyTCRGZYgF1eSTeEzwrDLVpbRwk4NnC3QKAkCTrDekd9jIB1inqBYIrhPkXXZTKQLMswGfGLsG0J8ztElcMTCLwfjc6ooxPi9ajkNYtLcCcx5VS8pKyGFt4mwgaeya1CeWjSv6ovkgwgzuSkOssBDsKCxOoo1UYvWleKtOVJjsP8eNuUE0J/FxJOJBgcmTHGt0jCr8D88wEh1hl0KWZtrTtLIj6aUgQFzZN8RSirfj7uTwx8S/Ievhm@CHw4RI@x3yCHMCbEjPDvM66qJ2gywm9rjpqhsllJBTPgEAGeW0wA6VtmHKeYYYDkRKpwtphjmVKgH/8hlp2zUBOsXKqczxRvEzRgpemaRoCgaKRvLzExKEAWk1gGQ8TVNIkUoU3ucjEA6UNr4gJgnK8Qu@X8ssmGViSvWqwQaAWdAXb9ebMZ4irBcNCVbkLXxuKOwxIZ7KGM7AbCGSy9aXoYQbQWJIbKlKPeovNwYYjMiMKunipjpFDtStMi8@vjw8Uugeoim1jUZSihjZvWMUdmSKBrOVrqYGA2@tptIs8YlHdc5I8eUu/JWJluOiTddWGGUWJX2opyetUOLVuV3xtQTJeOkQ6iiJhbsYxVA0jE440kuRiUwd@3fU7oZE@zM44/ZOduEcKxmyVUY6lzQMFECYUzWkYZBl3hRW8LiIZZoZE0ewkohtcoEkeVK1qJpMRRTr6S4IA0IOEEWbqiCcHT6NY3oKmPIBaYs2nPcA4ONLZusU0AZnfJv9AvEmO2nYlHXRVg0EhFWYrlNJe/upoqqEMRzjYqlcn1cji6K1p@EOCZ9WarxIsFVFQ6EtQh1YNZP8WYx4qwnJQrMsRCjypBmRYDdrNJbHa7RNZPETxZoxdlABtxJsQbgTrFqjpUkVVmhGgcp8yjrIGollDWUBiGqUOogmCoqUQhS6GMwScoOEPWk@mmEzxJqSs/cKTKA5KWJ09Q@KFXTE8kK5aJA2StREQvPcNsFn9Knif3/LVsl//Ooy1XFGXDWORlH/KfwGBFHcE2YfC4gheAEqMmYc3@IaEBsSBU3SGgJIkJwzqS/iokosl65AoH70HmEzsEx0mvTqjQOz@HxjXkLV4IvpDAqm4bwM6IQYBYXVbKrNlDhz/U8QGeAF8S/s1@K/J1DXQa8AsTzLmppCg1RKomQ7TsR71ITj6DeJGORLUVTj0XfRvrATOSJxR84o0V0DyEmF5RM2FwMPlbkfFlXRyLeOldP6eqiSWBMqgTkuSQllYJuRCkTqqTcPBEZ@ey9pALJP0J4nhhDIdUWZblp7l7V/1nRZFr2Fl2JGQbliYUm3Qox5MOkd62SEtC@ME1SV/HUInLJKnGpCdTVU2wy0msjGVOCJ1aqYlknGWnSrnntigpiNNrJQrQIlL0u5skLw/p83qbcS4aEVnSGwdfNrCh0O3OBAmDeTPthW51H8ZVNVbs1/9c181zYYewaCVOjhrUQtCCFwk6VhL8XbapQ6FbJdHFSE@0boVmAbYtmrguGgGGwZyAzbjrVXzXztMTmurw0XfSp5mC4RceCsIQqTUrLZWnL2AZI7uGYSVeiA9Q0etASc6LlpG3MiW6SNmEJC0MWFUtL@NC1UlV9Q9KGZDJvzZTPs44zdbOYCWGVCa7clPvx3DXJPbMK/rskYwRlAAF31cqKQSBZhD@XtbZICLDEDKMNcaoyiZfpUNFkazJp5fojVdeslnPRDlOl8poSIBmZQYYlUjQD4TPKCAu6RnRDRJLNRuAGL3MvYUorwAkLUm9cIm60QMUaoaqE4LmYbVTtLHqwGKzHABQ3vEmtSFF/8zIzt7pUO16TNaGm8nOY2pBbF1Qz2qNhRM2xBK0Q1dnuWm4IbV2FlHm09Joq0sEc0hWaFkUQey7HYctkooosP04laivTZgew71g5yDgAS5CH2y9bJmGsckqMg5bNRRWmPukAzQLD8409qV3LOogsVav7@wyVazZBykK6Q0o0EypfFJBjd79xmb2fNJQJwDqZy@iJ@UJsZyVCOxcaPAtjNXeIMmWm@kt9oBdHWUTcV7TR4AdE30QnoI6IiBE1qYCQo59WZLFCtcogSPWJYSXLSZ3ErJ4SfJ27kT@NO1DNIZIxuFFMT3SRL0409y1aKmNXB0ok6JzU42WngtWJg3BkytTzrq2JmpgPxe6NkrdDm0IUoUufityyolhjAh5HtA/9x4uyj2zR1FEDpnluLpMX27/LyFTpB0IVVCOYOIFmppolTTHImYBLug/ZRJFawE12miD@gkUWNxMxnpxCIft1K9qiQgiUmQGTzeC0RctzPmIHdFHLVpXC@O5msT@24usso3vZH2xFyY1MaSWbwxJTkY7vQI1tVCbJzIVOplmoE1hIqFdk/KLs6mV36KKp6JWkusX1onAOdL5WhhSrmqcmqBnS58VbBUvK@tBKtUZ9TlycmmwRVHQi1uOh2AYsQyUxTcUGTYBR7dRLfJWlM16WrZHEK3QKpqlrzAIYOUcUifUzyxW4HN5rmWvqTqH0sGoiRV1PeUgVN0AO67VqqWjENU7NtKaSMAqDqhMAsCiFIgIeJPfCKOW2JeRjqmwi6SJKVeF26hgx47QgVbgD5TmlFOEhLJPzI6o301VJcmpZhJ37c112O01W2lKKqG1Sd8naDT212l@R307qsNTvicUU7n7SmmLuLeWzj/yGhM9VFy1ieFZUmVf5XDr@LNqUDHNjDqLqYTFNW@TaBNUz5HltAmlpq0XuB4kW3cgVtiT0EcC5fliergv9VolC4mmOOOOpZTbXZDvZgrRqyg477PVMVMwg401a8uIMpilFpyDUlk3nmMwmJeHRsnHhmzJNKLMYGeQSTn1A9c6imWjfB04/iS276jA/7JBPzZkunYZr4QXlpvGcLS@xqToFyokKBMQfdZoot80n6zHmvqFnujq/Rkg6crM5bnCtWYtKI5UkADIS565W517CeAMeKHQIunMWTkpctNK1Q6dhMmBkwGPFbanOqula0aahSp6RzO6ayW4YQwS5bES/KjWDuCpPDpfaZAnGPrY1gaSUmuPDU20mFB76ZNNx0xWHuabOnFpPTzAqHEozTsFhimkKTYmQrTigQpAlxF/KA86kJhBYcVcnz6aFGQITHsjJ4i5LNWQS/WR1p8kTjDPOtHzgBmEdYtjdbpAdJWe2bCaOHGQFcnIv4kxb6lApkv@pPiHuK6viZCVILoVDeGaSVekUkJJuU8SsOmq3Pt3JZVuty/4rk6K1RBHGLIVr1CN3aeh8ASt8RHulC6kaA2o8alHjoXgP3kzogYd7M/tLVWySsLg4pDhIG4a/LxpJ1zMbAPIJJZAIc7N9OU7o9vVw581/t5//75er1z/98uL6w737V/8H)

Answer (score 2):

## 25. [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 13209 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
⌠¶┌fw|▓č≡H√ōkχ№ηļš¾‚ņ▓d^,ωb}aε▒¶qXSο∞æW&§L;ΞDσ⁾ΚW²8Ψļ‚│{	i$⅝QυķAγ√∙²‛5⁹ī⅝WΙ½ƨ5Z.h⅔≈¼δ∑⁽:Ψ◄║α8øVφā‚⅝.ōΚm⌠¼g‼⁾■σD(aV¼⌡┌π⌠→CÆš1κ*□─‽∙GMHck═η?ƨΨ‼w▲╬ΜZ²‼z<ηw@_šI↓ģΟ↓‛ζ2β⁴l⁽/mYnλ└ι○Is╗∞X[°╔Y¦X⁸a─≤Λ⅞g±μ⅓Χ╝'xwψƧ⁽╤¹׀⁷kc}NΘO⌡╚ηā↑≥&‚a┐∆O3ķ|┐%9G0čbh)ΒΦzb[┌dΗ⁹aγFΤΔ68Dη↔Æzn<▒Rο≈¼ΗƨτΓT│+¹⁰≡⁶⁸⅜*λΥψ№Μ→⅓ī7πƨw«?šēζ↔υļ}?8]≠╤š▲Σz]ο⁄ū‛⁸¬νj│ņΠ5:‽′š¶^ƨΜεθMW|7υ⁴¼ģ&#■◄¼↔æ≠Ƨ.׀ūjΝdΩχ.<ω⁸>§◄F?ΟξΗH³¡¦⁵↕∑\C.Λ∑ ν↕iα╝℮ā$xΝB)⌡d─□u¼k≠↔τ\rIWsdož	⅝čs0⁵čqæ»qξγφ{Γσ⁶ΩN8g▓²i▓ξοπ²;«τ¾πσņ≥Ηib~l⅜¤≠▒≈FcEH─╥Zq■⁹!╝½$^Ο⁽υ`⅜R¬ΧI└○ Φ_r║7x(▲⅟Ρζč↓LšΟλ└F‼Νc≠║`ωJ↓Γ4SeΛ>aXPΞ▼)‽ΩVΖH,≠∆╝∙o⁵°╔Τ‛ρ'Ρ§²:ν▒Ƨ⁴╤⅛BBŗ⁰ēfp■6⁰=,'▼ū≈⅜‛j≡χΖ⁵k▓‼Β'═Y*¦╬§Κ╥6░Ζι‽ιΤζē;∆⅜║l@←ηw⅝┐)ΡΧ§1ε¦¹λ«∆►)fOģ⅛⁰C░{§žτΙSJxANωRgņ╤/⌠0─▒v+⅔Β∑ψl╝x p↕Χ←⁷ο↓r⅜P▓Tv¼⅟¾⁷oχ‚≤ƨāΣ⌠ωx⌠⌡Zψ←⁽╬ē$┘Τ'Zš{@h'.^╚╤-‰↕Ν▼č) §Ε/█č&τqαζιu2ī|׀S╚%⅓?►‚Β⅛‰╚č±μ⅞┼╥▼±δ≤№IΠ8▓±Ω7³ΡT║at‚zχ@⅜J⅝.=ρ&_ģ⅛Ρķωæƨpψsø‰K»υY*R(╚‚ƨRa∑z⁽ņk¦S⅜►s	«Ωp4ιFRÆ;,5ķ9?wķ	▼r≡<\∑Mķ4æ╬↑āøΝθīY⌡ī╔╬⅓═Γ'θ{¡4ΝXB╝⁷*½§#ķvΕ_Σθ⅔|.█Νiκζφ≥√≡ƨGƨ█℮u√I3ēāα6v⌠Ξ⁽:‚¦ΤΞw1γæΨ′³⌠ΜΟ℮½ΩΧY¾Cκ√⁷ΠρUō∆‰ ↕⌡ν⌡⁾▲█↕┘/►GΕ½e→τ↕⅓‰o¹→S=5ā⅓PΚΒεj}ωρ;ūιGr⁷¶č═īξΡM∆╔┘π5¼⁵Ηķ⅜ņ→l┌hβΛ&r^ΦƧ⅛j↕<ZBļ§Ν`Βπž◄Λ││1,-ΝD;≡┼▲4‽?°Jqfēο|φ′↕⅟≈n⅔ω℮6Β68‽ZΡ»@eρīσi6^EΝ‛θū№÷4k°ωC÷ā¼≥◄▒′╤ξU_θō²³½Ζ⁶2¼׀Μ«C┘⁰8Σ┼ρΦ∫¬pīg≈‼Ε»AyŗTτ⁶sJfƧUA░║{πΘ↓U|θ⁾Χ⁶↑ķJΓΩ\U┌Θč‽*?└ε►┌℮!|½ΟčøeΖ|k⁵╚5ΝΦΙ‽⌠αZ&nυRηπ|■Γu!k:R$āΥ□p▲Τ║Χŗ□╗4īū÷YÆz⁷χW►▓g;šM╗┐ΡTfp<\╔«k░+Νr■ZƧΟυ▼<÷fq┌○÷┘πxXΣΥΩ∙»&³7>ø‚rσ↔╤<,÷Υƨ№²Ƨ┌∆z‰╤_┼ō/²‛¹ā/↔Ε⁄C5←¦⁷,ΖπJ⁰‰≠ō¼ωΒ╥oK]□v±ξθU⌠2░Eσb#∑K.╗nΒ№9▲ΥπΕ\.{i]Η▼≤~L	Οkμ÷⅞σΨ»╬R%⁵RJ⁸⅛ε⌠μ_e⅓]Λ⁶⅟▲Θ┘⅟Θρ□⅓υ\⅛no⁸KΝ┐æ⁸χΕ⅝⅝⁸iη←⅛⅜ŗΖ*Ψk░M]⁴f9◄oΣčχ⅛≡ξāL(yμ8Ο∙biρΝ'ν«σD=lkξ7λ╗{n ╥!◄=G≤ļm╬Ιķz▼Sāχχi╗*↓!l¼ŗƨW:{׀zu÷÷ΤHēqaVy÷⅓TR2└ΚK╝g■┐Q~⅞WnY⅞↔7²:κ⌡!Kv┘zjΣν┐(‛┐#MqūN↑½ΞΩ^¶Υ¹L6⁴⁶≡╥Ε:⁾:╬╗fι╚Sβ¤1č³yψÆķlφ◄i3+↕│─@─3≡V∫2┼b┘▲¹¶±C⁸Qq┌ζΩ%ō╚8L′3∆āYβ«φKyΨb╔Εl+ž¦a╝∙⁰W∆^AI,℮8⁶Gi№P┘αR┼→¡[wTΕ□O'ψH→≡ōa½vψT▼|(Jčq¡┌ø⁷e⅔⁹+╗,M║mōJ№└]Ρø$ž╝∆§;¬j≠ΦΙ←)℮ΠΖ1,⁾┌ρ~BrΧUΔΝF▼¤|¶F∆⁰z↓⅓.¾Σuψ.Φ⅝‽∞└ΡrwΝ╚υ℮∞Ω8⁶O≡η⅔ģ═ļ׀Wrγ3¾⅛c↔d‚_%╤╬]5,⁾⁰{ι¡4'{¡δ‚ρ⅜`▒\Ο⁽n⌠oνB«ΙΧš⅛√¹⅛ē‼√5┌W█{⅓╥f╝εFH'pærPī⅛ŗƧ╬Zδ׀}56=Φ‰θ3Ω─)øčZ─ξ№#¹Z≡ē:′ā6Rδ	 ∑y?⁵HƧ¼⁽ΜΔāΦ←ν█ā⁷⅜F└√¡g;Ζ<=hιμrφfģ║²η⅜⅔○Θt≤m²`āļƧFΔ⁵←:ΥΤļ³ΟO∞37eīα6║⅓⁷℮ļΗυ|↔j0;⅓d←t←υχƨkģø─▲(jζ⅝ÆΙλt□ZΚ⁷⁴¡∑⅛O≡K╔ø▓¼Χ‚;↔Κ═⁵Ρκ¬¹TR)t_)⌡+Β‚ο4#:5/HΛķ{░υ;¦≈═╬&κīkžυψøoZt±υļčυΖīG+Ψ<N≥μ⅝┌ζ#ψ‛U׀G◄rI∆a!⁷ēK√ιW$ΘΜ⁰πsņ┘$b╝š≥⁹⁹ļ_6⁷8Ο►┐ķ╔↔υ∞7νa«El≡ΟjΚv‚⅔j≠²ž∞□`ΕWžΜΖΘσv≤‼B2t≥@ŗ╤ā‚J│°Wp╝Wē↕¡№_←;Ε∑═▲ā№BƨF³ŗΨ╔s*≥=GƧ⁸ΛΚ«█νāρt─γ▒.■:⅜↓ģ+┐Πø↔→wrτζΡU7žYž,uΙ≠ΩIΕ/∙č█=U→≤_∆0#m²(Ηrρ}┐Z\⁾⁽Æκ√:⌡²?∆≠eΚM øB>⅜Ο)R4░Θ¹¡Ep_HΔ)╚ķ)ūΨD.⁽∆]ŗs‼≠⁵Gu⁸⌠{Φ□Ψd	ΙqqTΟ.│{«6Km⅟sc░_ƨ‚2L′¼āÆ№⅟⅔▼■█∞¤u;/¤σ(◄«‼⁰║Ƨ‽,μ?p¡└γ▼7E⁾ξƨΒμ↓¦⁷↔9»\9αŗ‰μvņΣμ;9i‛±↕_↕Qxο⌡dT═ķ°v⁷τ╝23]ζA╥|L¤v=,¡⅔τ≥′A ╝ξ≡)⁵$≠\׀ΗB√ΜS⅔ΙωPr╗◄∙F→╚ģčH▒ηΧ►ΔKL	p6d*[⁶±⁄¶|⁵l[+┌Γ)ΩEƧ§ļο*υzγ:,╚6ο@³:v¤cχωZ62↔⅞ιg╗═τ4⌡\ņ³ōf┌ΥfQ]¬q4Sγ!→xh#`№i┘⌡○uh¼XxB∆≤V⅞⅟‽□′╤(θ∆∆Κβ»«■⁶<²׀¡5Χδbσ{Κ╚┘_[׀u:⅜Bkv⅟β∞j└Q ūa=5a\οH╝eyBΛΤζ≠ΝNζ²γ§═*‼<ƧΠķ⅓!№‽q=m┼Y|ūξHl¤ν=(⅟V§Ι+◄IPv$═?hhm▲\⁄8▲'⌠↑0≡Bξ¼⁷¾πeξwθ└b?≥§hrΗķVģx⌡↓⅜│Κπ′?ΘVe‽^‛oģ⁶mΕēΘξšC÷↔EΡ'ρ░╗Γ%Ν≡υαΠyκ↑B⁶ΛkXΖ{▲ιp⁸β&┌ODoJ ╥¶ļÆō~Æ⌠zUΓd[teū`	ΩO<ΓθΨ≥φΝeō√⁰E⁸/hī‛[┐ΕΓ}∆r0 Ζ↑׀a℮~8%█\ū╬⁷⅓«‚Vσ≤⁵ΘΨ⌠»,╥ķ§ø:№±┐→#‚š z°i█&īγ╥N²W|ģ³{U○≈≥≡SΙδ-H◄ōX∙ē┘_Ξ²$⌡‚σ↕√ny○↑‛Χ¶»ΛwΨp┼⁴νAƨ(Βh¤μe ╝š‼§3φH◄uA≠#L└Βā¦Yŗn>O⁾Βε↑′÷¡⅛sΞ[η$VS¾ ↔‽ZrγēΤβZΜ⅛Κ▒ξ⁹O°β>δ↔οx8■Μ¤³╤ι'g░xkmαlρ⁽┼Ζ∆׀↓!wγ½╤│¾]∫š»No&■Np&zņ/≠m▲KF╥)¡sβ─YU'λg-z⁹╔|∆┘žΡΓ{øķSΥbIζTļžB-3Φ→⅛`ψ6:▓⅟'M#7Ƨ,j○P∙ @ī№$Γ¤∞E@²>»↕¼¤⁶1¬mφøωσfηļƧ‼╥ΡH′rοīsγP↔′^?l5╤⁷-N¾ν⅜ΝΔνF≥▼►ž»!>č»⁷ε0T╬ZaJ∆ŗļ⌡█hx׀○VΕ╚°Γυ‼⌡P_▲ ═FÆiωΕ¾ģč/⅛ņ└ģΣΞ№»-▼Ψ▓βΦ¤∑⅛▼Λδ╬′ī¤ol¤═@Ξτ‰F=⁸E⌠◄╥γ¼Z>ν&-R°⁴ΕΛ±wκ~9↔ΨΒ~ΖΨ≥►\∙▓‚¹─)ā<ΞB▓╤θ▓ΣΞo√X↔«B@B┌±α≥}@⁰¦½ķhh¼ξæ|ΟN¤2~○{┘^↑t‽Ζ±eoš↑y'AΛ³←o⁶{⁶7HÆ⌠H±‚ƨmυ‚?κλ↓dƧφ{J∫┌⅝¦θBlΕκ░⅔}`ΘχJ┘UA≈κ└7wšz⁷jS<I Τ╝«(`≥½Ι%i⁹⅔!○JΙ4 -wģYo7o.4qķΛ]ΕντZ¼ēτ⁶γΓΞWμS*ε\∑⁸RGΩ׀Κ⅜Θ′z□j⁷∑‼ļΔ┌C\κ‼#,+≥φ^γæΛΒ▲≡²Jt∞⌡▲1■p′┌πΤο┐νņΙο≠;Γ¾ΙN⌠→N¬¦→║⅓Κ⁸½⁶|²σtg⁶?⁽f9*⁰@Hž½Υτn¶¤ļ<Pψ⅞q⁴⁰zG_≠Dg╚─τ⅛æΛ┘γJ1ΛVJ$Rν@⅜Ξ! ΒX׀Υ;Ι§y╚∫τ▓βτøε⁴3ν¶Q∑{c↑Φ□Y№‰u!±?ΩOη}¦οM{▲N≥j∞Qκ:?ψžēft∞╝─Ƨ⁽_'∑αxšeη,s⁄⁷/νΔΩ╗≥kΘ◄Yļ⅝nƧ‚žTģεt¹v╤Z+«Χυκ╝⅜′~∑~σ/⁶ψΧYfηsλ░‽℮j═ƨc.σ=ζ⁹pƨl¡ī⅜;77∆/√4▒ξ╤Β⁽JΨ⁰mM*±‛,qΝ⅜7⅝/c⁹⁰ļTρΨΡ⁹š(*Ξ╗,Ο┘∙D¾ψΕο⁴φ≥oa⅜⁵^╗⅟@Oc‼I{t¹∫kū═↓¡,Σy↕Μ±[B○d∫׀№←⁵Uψ|τ╝↓&┼η▼ψ,№↓№ΔKF↑-S5ΜΤ±⁄ε‼Pž;aο⁵J◄Θ↓⅛┐_Zo¼V+╥s⅜š■ξΔ{;Μ|CC∙ΛΘķψ25W*→Bp⁵⁵ļ`Ν,∙.8=a║‰L¡s═ΧoψνCBuCλēd6▲θλ▲fΕ³Ρ╔∞↔ļΘκΟ▓○{∆#φ}T⅛φGΛ*r≈cΥ]ΜQ∙M↑═ β9 φ⅞α∫jQ┼ι:\ρ¼z°║#ΠΒ(↔ūη[¬←,∫)f,¤λJCl∆	┼τVπY↕⌠TΦ‽³¾ōz▼<v¡t◄⅔□ģθ░πļø≈Qοķ⅛Ω┌Ρ»rΔf1‰Ψ³.¦ΘEO←^≡↓FVΛI=ģpκ1╬⅝⅜δLŗ:⁴⁾ok2░_,ΛPYv4ēΡΚy*■O⁰00⁴ķτ▓Bυ⁄ēφΖ┘y‰mMyηδ⅔ņ⁹*9kgōΟi}o╤Pr‰⅞ΓPv‛°⁸┘○³E┌↔ΙYrčΦ⁽Ο⁾Βμ‚οø│.ƧDmEBΛ⁹«ζ▒ιυ¬░.71█▲-(′>LFy└ρ≈¼Ε-?⁴4Yδ¤#a│VjσwΧ{┼↔┌«⁴Ν⁰`)Δu╗¤⅟ρ≡Kr}Q▓‽b)█⅛≡»DeæQ2-⅜D¡≠π▲¬▼cΥ┌¬ģy»¼īΗΗΙ;qp√ū⁷«2╔┐z¹FΠ÷Ξ/yΓ≠BΧ║⁰⌠►χ'□Cgτu‼↓⁶θp:Z!¹αēzαd3λķV$Θ═⅟|>÷u≠<ξθΥhƨ≠0%≡,⁴∆1±τ5W~	κ±I└╝≥╗T¼SģΟε→Γs5kκžŗδ‛ΞΦ∫¡§⁸>P‽Ω7‛≠/÷∞OVhHl3]¦ņ⁾W⁾«»υļΝ.qζ╔y#υ‽ωŗτ#-¡eΩΕΟGCv{╤Ε▲┐׀║⁄Ν┘░ξσ⅔⅞19τpφ⅛¤~ΞQ≡JΨ↑√VfΞο≡ρ%]σ█(7ūļč«'⁰╬ƧøSκž{◄|.Χη§⁄n1r9dδB○6≡ΓI╥≈Δ⅓-∆¼š%Λ⅓d○?qοD8X≤÷ξ←μ%□ķ○ε⁴⁸¦]Π⁷Æ['‛ø▼‼ο←}⁴0↔¹'Βψ`cΔ7]┐→Σš═īWæ↑LEγB■■!c}┐$:IZdΙ±№ΧEfΧΟ▲≠⁄╚ņ0`√Ωŗ§≈ΞOΜT-ŗΒ«╗Μ*Æ≡□ņJ℮→Ε⅝N~j▼↔οO⁹ļ╬i∑$.┘s6NΗ-æ□□JU╚≡,σ¶τX׀■σ□«υ ⁰∙0æε╤t┘½J║οSķΗ╚╤⅔=5dvG╔█▓ƨ	A⅔O½Y⅞°‰~,{ΘTƧΞT[ιa⁴⅝ιj5¤→Β◄+≡ā◄ŗ№Ξ.±$TΚ↕Π⌠ÆΨ⅟Κ³E⁷ZυB⁷b─Γ(⅛⁹v÷εX⁄'}qn№n^Η№▒Γ█RΕBη⅝k,┼Η«≠tΘēβ¼Γ⁰κ⁾SΔξK9D¤⁸nκ[{æΞΤ╥g⁷§▼∞^m%⁹↑uοW□ξl∙T$ΚzΞ╚¾ø‰=xKč<=ΛEδΛX<±jz)θ⁴⅟)‽jŗΤƧƨI║∞≤c!φÆ;:⁶U⁰I+a▓χ└TΛ⁶╗<◄⁷ƨ#γdΦη>»æ3Δ′⁵}Φ¦⁶CΞ≡R⁰∞¾iģt□¼Pyω▼▒a¶←╚╔┌∙m≤KCƧo∑<⅜»#‚θ#Aι'║╔‽┘ω⁶Νž↑½◄Al⁷Οl■Δ╥Δ∑I0ku‛ILχ¾⅓,│4№ο□&ΦvO¡ο≡ō>³,⅓NEčΤ■┌k⁹#$8τ?dwAarKΒ 5@č4¡QgΠJ№▲Ξx□‛}\‼³«╔⌡1RƧ\<L?=⁵@ξā,Μ╥↑⁵<mΘ³¤Γ≠─Ψēτfb6~μ└Κ\⁷Υ =L°ααQjū8χ«CX3│Ιōλ¼hI8gHθ>Ξ▼æ‛κ╚⁰ΓΖγο¾B}λ½■9─SHq↓τωa ž≥Ξ⁵⁄⌡δ╬‛¬u⁴÷)v↕»׀Yπ¦O╤^3zΣ∫⁰@Æ~n■qΕJ¦↔↑⁹M|½≈ ξbρ¬R_TvΧBƧΟ⁹8ī≈L≡T<r∞(p3Ζ≤|!b,Yτ¾g№,.«Fŗ≥«;σ÷K∞,1?│╔§■⅜ZεδeHm[9+Υ↕½Ι℮¼┼(x∙└∆]mV½⅝│b4n√H↑►ψΒ⁴║h>w¶ž≈8κƨΙ╥pΡ⅝4Η~ē√7░-▓ΟΘ÷@*)Y2╚}⌠√¼⁸_═YχPēLKΝs[↔¾⁴‼~▲eø׀⁄OΕ;ΜhχλZ¾DuΣŗ‼⁰Cļ2≥ │Λχ╗⁰σ─Ψ∆╔n∆⁄νTi²ΣtβΧl⁷℮⁸(Σvξ°≤↑w↔═+¼λæπΔ/θψ-Θ∆XQσā\S¬‛№o▓xΟ▼šfqM○x±∑kl§	{λ╔υ○P¹8ƨΘžU¹KZπ׀č,¼ņr′ō┌Υa.Θ%′ģ_η׀Ε+⅞╥⁸→Om┐ΠΣ∙□‼Ζ,Q⅝εVΤ[ι`čLļ∞B¶$¤ģΧΡeμζ╥↕≥XRR»ātnM÷╚MΜ‼θmO1ƨ◄Ο□¦e¦┐‛ρ▼°ΙsK∑-t⁄qāg.q;⁽η⌡šΦT§↑Γ⁽UīX3┘5ΕD['&f¬ρ'F,ω╚◄;V^ģš9ΛvΦοχΔūečω.?÷≈½Χ└⅔ΗΟļ°ƨ→½p⁴3|←æTοΦΣø└S:.φ┐:	šž°≤ωwq½zξ∞čω(∑#ω⅜⅞¹.uυ	(κν∆UΣA≠∆VYc)»Ι⁄╤℮≡⅟ŗDSτ2?∑⅝○≡⅛ΘξC↕A∞Ƨ║#«ƨΧ2\k⁽׀='Νūκ⅝⌠=m⅜BΕ─^²&ģyΙ╬DΟo±Æ▒&׀׀■ wV|↔⅜≠»►σγ'§Τ¼ΠPο⌠8]+2AκjIπ>Υ⁰Jaŗ≤qκ_Kψ¬YZ6Bā ?G\@ξ⅛mΙ}g9→±▒*n47¶►Θσ≠QSΞx¹εN⅞¹⌠‛Ζ○π↓Ρ3c╥∞↑√x⁾žļΨP╚l(øΥν}█Μu↓Ιπā'Γ‛╚Ν▒↑%0Kγ*ωαφdSι′rE∞/⁽}(!¦>βT⁸OÆÆ]γν3Ψ8≡∙uÆΟlp↕ēģ^∙<mlŗ∙ηxuL4Oκ┌ķ[⁷i5Aμ‚βLa└ķ2^Q2<⅔η┘8}□▼▲ιQ}ΡEΚpķΘυζΚ─7⅛³‽ƧC»§┘wθΖ∆ē6α8Xο⅜0r8νQ⅟§¼Ƨxξ∫`╬θo:%LKUΣ)⅝2⁷τ7»¶§š→+¦¶ļ_5@═ī53⁵0⁶׀⅟\Z¾Q⁴ģ‽αōyīR╚○┼⅞γ|ÆπξH‚ΚΩ,└gāζ┼o}φ3;ķƨEkΔ 2Pķ═zψM╥β►}h▒│m≡M‰r∞┐ζΘ↓(Ugd3ģ°ōRω⁄σ╬┐ψē↔y→ī№⁽⁷¡○*φΚγ{F\╚ω℮*γ≈p│aΖτrΕƨo	oÆ¾]aøa‰2Ε╗ΘPcBēζq■	d←╗Yπ9iΣ&┐k⌡ΕΨ⁶ŗK'I╗½Æ▼T╔i≤⅛¡ΒΚXB]$℮π░Β≥╗ņ▼?Z╔s*Sψ○┼4υ-kōar²0ν╤∑ƨχ&┐čN¾ģ¡{Σ¶⌡δ{1w■z←═bÆgfWf¬a╥`x⁽ōī↓²λEqB8(C>GP─Η	I]ηθδ26Ƨ@ξ ]№?I⅟že≈□6≤◄O³6░Ψτ]k/√h╝:↑.\γ⅟↑ρ!║β,Ƨ└χRΕWƧ÷ζ№mpH±§V)<¶īTWΔ‚%→ΘR~Aē#,(u¼∫↑ο▓¡╔⌠#v^eΚ^⁄7³co¾'¼╝'▼▲ωζģ∆3Λ⅟□{(ēVžø∙└ρΝ║1βD⅔ā¬ΤG⅛≈f╬*χ(▲x∞mš⁹$Zu⌡j'φ¶‰p=8▲⌠4┐lN└θšū←ø@dz«Ρ‼eγk○Θ█υQj»7ļ3≡⅝╬⌡ξ^√1⁹√>W′τb§∙Δ⁾׀╤²ozŗΖ⅜ψe½1]╥¹{Ογ-Ρ│ƧΝIX|@ΖΣ‰█i►%¶ly2*β⅜ξΟ║d:S=7τσT℮±C¶≥Ω{'6↓■⁶CΨ387Λ▼░∑═⁷Ρā	⅝/'E∫¬╝░s:Ω⁹~κ∙⌡§I÷w◄|+F└χ¾⅔k³[0⅟=φ8G+⁄ζƨ►ΝR8κψ?sε▼Ν.ņ6hz_ν§⅟▼Β║⁹?A@K{8⁄ρδ⁾»}Ν↕χo↓≈≈‚iJKπg_℮¾+χ┐¦.²9<<ņOžσβ%ēl⁴τ⅓U⅝■⁾:╤ρGWL□ņΦFΛ≠kΠ(|⁾$Εbλhμ⌡\⁄ο⅟ρ⅔NΝ′V│æÆ¤³2π⁸ιo─Γ«8v³║ cøfψ+╔A╗pp%ΜO¶′Η⅔⁴⅟┐h▒ΞδΟ⁰_X◄ļ-Hρπ┘4w^θƧō=ψξ⌠ļ¼¡⁵κf÷s▼@-4Xgļψ⁄»⅜Μ,┘ξ4!░⅓pG³#↑Οož-_$}Rσ»īσ▼╤╚╚ΕBā▲jī^∫┐t	ƨμxΝ↑‰žΗ6SΝλ¦E2'4ō╬M≤ļ«οFW@νryμ≡(Ov┐⌡HA3[¾æ⅔ζ≤ρlG′ωA╬ģ»!¾xζ⅛≥↓≈■⁾╤_g№▲⅓′«⁄5æ⁰ļ∞Η⁷‼ūE⌡⁽░Β╝E←Σ/⅞R$λŗUET(]p2@ļv6\GιΔ¡Δ┐1⁵it⌡YB±r↑№QL┐	¼ƨ└<|#╗(,L┼⁹πu-κ‽H%TΒL→►]╚/vΥr↓o!gμGz5╤\Σ0KG⅔_2ΤΕ←οīgΦυΞ±■7№⅔‽Ν↕Ψh⅔■ΥS>²»▲←►HD^uķβ¡⅛ξ{┼wÆb⅛⅔▓æ=ōU└⁾JΗ⅜sd³u≈≥Nv³/uŗ≤¹bžžτ|ΡΥq{\⁾~W2θPΗ:←f-Υ~»pΗnοJ█¡⅝Ε≥Η..Æχ%^y`§∑⅔÷Μ%ρ⅟T∞►	¶δķ┐!ZVΤΞi▲<ΟS}7▒⁾≈?№Μ	αj‼⁾Ι7!Yψ«ΘΜVūψL/HΥ#↓8±θzA2ƧΝ℮;CΩ	/π∆№└¶║δ[~χΦΒ|cΦEΞķ:CνΓ;Χξq«šΚ○⁵EWR↑ΡiS≤:~O≈ķ`s`ρ⅔εΨ⁸.׀Θv□ωņfe±≥π¾¶≤u→!ΛV@4Vπ}wωjρ¡vΒ╬}Ψ∫η²;′↔č⌠ξH╬8=↓⅔ηΧ§Β³θΩ;{∞:g═Yw▓?,⁰V─►‽Φ⅜%‰²Η⅔Κε<:+jΥ█┘ξ□čΠ÷Bē\Λī	█X{±¦:oN¹Κρ]∞I≈!χ6r5!ιL◄ΦTΥæB¦Θ¡η2§Mjη{└▓⅟℮,┐¤Cæ m¤Γ╚φkpļGU║	)²c↕‼‛#⅞■%¹∫8ξ′┼OΓΟ1ZI░F±‚pΣ◄ΛķΞ^u‛ēθ6⌡J≥‚↕¶⁾žSFpQΤ\ƨ§∫⅜'¶t{η║⁴»‼□W³‰βaƧK∑1ē◄Σ←t╬»≈σKΧ↑δ y²≡~⌡⁷⁹┐─═ΕæE′F⅟ε⁾ΛM«B⁄θΩ-c#∑GΩšV‚KN»§ae::s╬ξθ→h⁴Yū¡ē6⁽½‽∆▲№ψ╗*↓'′↑οæσ⁵¤.∫ωPκ°Ƨ►π√T6╥⅓≠p[;φ≥─ζ>S‚╝∙>CθÆωļo─⁹V8@5+║Q«▓k■tαω°α⁾γΙ╚□-ū-∞¡E(│ρ]#Z┘GυΛ○=γβnņU▓■,²⌠□%′N⁾ī)ΩJ9ūX╚<+¼J	╥Μ┘¡QΤ⁷^a⅛≠olΝβ4ξ█βΖ║⅝ƨ⁽?⁷|⅓æD	6y¼x9′↔Y⁾čč⁽NκjKzvφī∙⁾ķΕX9∫=ģπ╥}∑′ωbπ└ΧΒycs¶׀≡&√└āpb‰xÆΔ²ηE:a‰▒WT↓eΥģΕIΕ⁷9ā║Rd4$8ω□@Γ(─s▒[∑EP│┘Ξ/φ¶⅞/æη■7$‚⅞η⁴@↔āΝgvΜ±κΦ;≤⌡ΠDq○JžΞ!η¤′└↕Φa≈(χ∑a∫ļ─;.○9|η⅞pgωδ¶▓εfKT*[ΝΜø⁶└▒p◄№9|	○\,jβ▲mrαΚ‚I╥Γ┘B∙Q⁴╬Ætē‽═ν⁶Ο┌M⅜?ōņΙσ°○⅜◄ļ►vΥoaģη^φ¦‽⁄↓#}ΚZΛX)≠R┼TNβŗ↕ο}«¬βο)ģ]&⅜%─↕č7ūΠΠ⅓ο└⁹Cæyh│Bκ⁸*⁾↓2ƧκsWγΨ{χ↓Osω┘/=.λΗvģΔ√5⁸⁸h¶ΤA⅝6P׀!○Xp2)[└‽vR⁰W#≡¾B□U:√1⅝¤-E%τχ-Nu% J╚οaλυ╗Æ~CΓk>≈e ↓→¶½⅟pš↔Ν?⌠MWΥ>_>⅛‼ΕΓ¶β³d□K╚∑‛w⌠wf≠)X1w⅜D‽/■ωƨ≤Mķ÷ |Bκ¼⁶┐.[sļøχ`╥Τ)RļRæ░⁄⅛εΕē{ršκρc⁾∫Oφ)%⁽~¡⁶‚T┼bOh4gBΞ&ΡΛī┐║λB§Ψ)HV┌cæ&Ji4←8│-τ¼≥║ ƨāūy═]\\℮kwλ┼v≡ΛΙ↑υX█≡&⁄1χ→╝8+‚Γρz3°│8ζκ│kM⅛βP○τcΠ⁾-ΩSY~5ņ:(δķ≥⅞μΦ%«σΠζ׀0+ωΦ,εψ>Μ3[;⌠ņš║Yf'╬‼⁷¶‽ΦqΕv←⅛x▓/Wv³f|p-	ΝOγ‛μ⅔¹(ΝΙtΦ¤}▓Ι«Τ-3∑ιρ7tT«²υķ[~~╝√↓⅟BUa↑=§jΖφ⅝≥δ┌xDδε¹}⁴HnK⁵⅝ģƧΙδψc▓ΓK↕√bšβγ3┌ņUø∫ιFqωΟæL@o*1χZ≠Β√&¦L6k⅝]≈3ΚV±9ΧβcΨΞ⁴f░←U║┌←<τ∙IXΔJΦξ8ν‽≈√Θa‰‚¹c_ω‚⁽Ο±ο .Βømc_@øģyb∞M▓α∙τs⁰I′‰,⅓‽⅝Z▒⅝)¬M_ω]¹μ:╝↔]░]ņ≠θCM█■√δ│¤ο¼┼⁷ƨ⅜∙gƨ⁄Μ]¼ƨK~⌡žj╚;Ud≤∆ΞΩ[⁷jπi′┐ēθ│ω⅛%ηG↑a¶k⁾ΞVΞSķ&X'Υ< ƨƧ′l`≤Βēnļ⅓o⅟║PδY9Φν‼┌±ē4'%Cs{Ξ╔D%|└χw╥Y↓υ∆⁰δlLΝ‚jī╔EļJ⌡ΒS/#│⁽ƨ6►⁴	ūÆ⌡h‛▒.‚↓s∆≈⅔μ╚M_═ō⁰/┘ā-↓>ģuK≤¾Ο′Η5φ⅞zc℮ nfŗpδ▒j?γ⌠%Ρ⅟g#Τ²/ēEεκAσ¤ē$0Z7╔⌡⁵ƨ⅝↑½▲ε⅜οοģ⁷j-κ¶Ι¾⁽§■≤⁹»UΔ]p8ζ^⌡⌠<¾,⌡ΛΜ⁰⅓ω╚μ′iθχ׀\;_u≤ø¹y⌡׀ķΣ∆׀@GcκΧ±¤šed┘≈=G↔Q=≡Ξi⁰}>▼7‛0σz¡№╗v′▲┌_○Sļ6‚⁹§r¡═⁄DtΦ║▼Κ¾╝ōv⁶=≡Z&f?◄Κ▒3,ž∆ē╤╥Æ→Jōv-Υα↕n¾W⅝ļ▼7⁄ļ→ρN`C׀ΙΠD⅔=Ρ⌡(÷°wsχλ◄¬N¦ν‽Δ÷>Ρ#▓D>+ēī?B⁸2Κ‽OG√ωΠ⁷PƧ‚αb└οΞ5Ad⅔÷Ο³2ēρ℮Z#2δ#▲≠æ⁷>≠⁾4ΚƧ≈∙CV░K┘P⌠└‼⅝<YωΒ∫vr⅜P≡.⅟xƧ⅓`Η[Da¡ƨE⁷►─5║Kbλ≥▼i∞Μ¡$‽y`R‛W?Μ▒○ρ:°K⁽Pū⅔a╔x='χσ↓γ└√V‼ιy→≥ν;ī⅓δ∑\+v‛C┐χ`6Δwo²Æ[eHģλ¼β⁵○⁾ΓΡ↕½Ν→hκ░tΙ⁹ķRξ³Λa⁸:x7↓g▼≠Δrt¶╗iΣωαÆ![⅔xαMtο)ΔqFφ§⁰⅛@ļp'οMƧC-↓‚ī¬ΨbM\⅜⁰≥(⁶Π℮¶σ═╚■8℮‚°GOΘī╝′‛\⁽øΨ↔ΡG}ξ⅜∆⅓ī׀▼▒]Y±↑κ╤	½k⅓╚№rMYžγ;∞⌠FΡ⁸{ēυ╝VΞ≤Σ▼]β¤_ε▼½YJp¹°ēņƧ=$≥Ν]┘↑≥Οī⌠▼⁵%Y÷TΨ»τ█RΕk'Δs⁶8ew⅝√O\Mņ∑⁶_¹abrT∞i⁄)Aen┌∑⁵⁴N┌Τ?Ζ@Π¦5ø!ΨģjΥ≡▲8N⁄k→`½0Q{Ι⁽(,≡/δ{ņ∫1`↑θβt►═Θn░ž⅛¾č97ƨxō2Τ)╥K-&qJEÆ«▒οO;rεi‰⅛:DΠ²○⅛6ž↔8C►ō⁹Ρ╬⁷‽(╬μ:π²M∞vWMcΩXjfn\¡Χ³ķa⁰γŗ+⁸α{Æ┘y▼▒<τs░ū[¾Ε─?⅛↔└◄ī=Β2τ¦¼░A§T^RΗ∆←▼□λup'█σγ╝CΡΜī#Ω=ģ‽α|⅜SIķ?x╤*ΞūnΞ▼ ↔Νn╥○U{B┌kΓΝ№□_ōΘzā∆KΚ\ƧΒō¶P9υ╬Pī║Δu└ω▓Ζ ─αŗ ↕║►‽⁵§≡VΒκX³Oθ≠ΠxΘ¡∆υPZ9ξ▼d/τ■.eΝ¤¼1X▒∞⁵∆⁶GΜi∆⌠;+EzX╬▒Λ◄0φīsKΘo┘oΘ9`Κuī¦ķ⁹uŗΣT7P╚λ³╬‰a⅛7δΞ⅛K┐τ⁄‰≡Ω¼¾≠½α0æL↕,▼ƨƧΨ⅝׀⁵▼Πø▓sZē¼¬f4╤⅓š:→φχ¦&⁵⁸′a¡z xW‛³m/[nΧ#P‽bU╬⅜∆λΝΧ±Υ↑XZ‚wT▲$‛GƧ[±ρ↓¡κ)■∫²%ι⁵a⅛EU′ø↑◄¾[.≤L≥┌ψ⁸&Λ=‚{-Fč█æ@Æ0π2κΨ⁽○⁾)01Æn±κ‰‰◄Ƨ¹═¹⁽↔ν═□⅔|≥η‛nIτAΣ³‼μ‰─⁾1ņ(«░,νΗλ`‛≠¾¼ΘX]‽H,[-<E.ρπ'L³uφ▼)	┘!⅔μ┘╬;Ιψ4Wψ╥g¤ZK│⁾≈I▒!īīλθL⁶ø≠℮Δ║▒╗′▼JnΔ$$Γ╝ΖεaτσP⁸‼⅟Qι.X¦№∫]θ~aī,p7!γ│AJ¹Æ:□²β‰↕0K*β≡FΖ◄X▓æ║↑YηΠmY>²OÆ⅛+¡§C′▓ļ0¶d⌠>π H÷š@]τδΓ└⅜‛⅝‼λ§¬⁰‚ΖžΘ⁶≈y←³δ&⁰φm∞[▲C9ΗΗ╚Κļ«hN\¹VωΖ2ιΤχηBz╥█β╝╚▒∞8«'‛±′Ix╥∙>╥⁶′≥>Ο,Q^E4Κeh▓Y uāΘ╥ΘΛ]GΙρ⁽∫e@c⁵‛░∙Tτ╬j_╝&εļ⁾∆#F_╬Ψ║Æt№↔<≤b≡½z6ny┼e¤‚▲ū¬bk┘¬β(M⅓U=-℮ž►z8ΟjΥκ√┼j`p6be)⁵ΓK∑Τ>■ūo′\‚‚eΠEƧ9%∆H*⁴4KΞδ-oc░ΦāΦ}Æf≡ξ□ΘjRΠ⌠Πnκ¬⌡¾¬≥ŗΜX⁷╤»bg═3Ifi≥G⅝≤≠ŗΒīč:ē¤[3⁹ƧWŗι?⅞M⁹O≡Ζ‰⅟⁸`ΩΒ(xZ74#⅝Nī4‛T%ƨ)‽⅔÷}⁹⁷Cæ⅜V↑³G¬αXc◄↓zη⅝⅜►∆š1uUD=IīTO⁵5G,∞⅓Β:╝p╬⅜?║kX≠D`Φ¬⌠└U⌠+κ⅝▓⁾1Υ¤ūW⁷⅟λ║3⅔vΟ⁷□āŗRχ◄βj⁸Δe└NΓ‼υ«*ΟΕn‚⁴»ΚūωlQ	h█○ζķdf{׀χ╬Ρ≤Η/ņL¶ēUΦŗnqEFη└8|;Δ▲ƧΖ¹Ε┐b¬╚⁸'⁄Æτ⁴≠╤ΖΠ7╝;Kr¬Pq┘Jβ╬~║nΟ`┌?|6′ηχΞ≡øφ╤W⅓¶Μ│⁾\╤Cš↕⅟′d№B1*v_d{Æi¼_bøφ≥	ΕΒΕM⁹‽υūæhW>x(‚′℮□╬CEeSķΔō╗┌∫!'-{π⁶ψ-∫│9f¾⁵-ōix?ο‛F≥⅓D2ν,▒⁄◄Νa▒r⁸⅓ķY»χ℮Ρ-eQ»0δYč↕ρ4δ4~Νz□Ηi⁷8№ω⁶÷ι}▒Νƨ?└║±2g╝⁾οΣdWļχΗ¬\╝⁸ΟOψ⁾⁴Δ⁄ΤΘ┌%≡īPQ░½]ō5afτ█+,ν9▼Ι≈▼Η\ļƨ┐⌡wg§j	%.āæ└′5╚^Γ↑⌡Χ∫P∆H∆≈≈Ξz³№■∫±Β³⁾γn¦┼yΚΘ≥;ΚC¦'ŗ`κ⁹ΧƧγPdγSmυ⁹○Μ▼s℮ķ(N⁸θψq■A?┘□<⁰Æμ∫J▼□Ν(D|≠⁷iΒ⅜⁾½°WkL¡╔/⅜∑⁴ηš○⅜ρ═?│□q¦&║ψīα±¬z²‚Iūe±γ ╤‚g∑|;]^M┌∑6č╬Ν⁵∞→`δΧ'nL└&℮nz└⅜!(Τa	š«/ΗΙF←Θ⁴t(ΞB┐γ←┼ κΕDΙ≤∆]⁽╬ΕjW=@Ω∑ø─β└⁴q►=═P↕Tp┌ļ╝′2(ņ═³)Θ¤½╔Ξηāμ³b↑ŗ▲⌠	&¾ω\%◄┘ø█  Λ═+╥*JΨ5FΜ|8»@zοΒÆQ$⁄u3ā⁄W*č╥d¾~⁹Y}Ρ╚‼^κ)▒ƨ℮k█{∫⁷nΦE╚g.¦E‰╚f←cWμķ²¡κ⁾◄»κΓ3@§iK▓T↑◄#²[Bp√!◄υ±«κ□℮ž\UΕ⅜⁷nμ9Κ41⁶.┌┌○S≥⅝⁴ψε⁶>+⅓⁵ΠΠN╔░←@Β$+ΒΓ%čQ□αLμ⌡j⁴Μ8‰v9}4╚‽ļƧ0Qš╝7√^»▼4ŗIV¾±ņχf‽Π╔)πρ¤¦gÆē⁽ΡiΩ ⁹∫_$└Λ¶ε▼j\qΤ1QΥW▒∞Ψ,κ╔'č╤jā'93EyƧx∑I⅓≤─π¬‼π┐⁰≥↓u╤;αυ∆π²◄7^║ρηš≥wƨgŗ>xu½!ņaΡYu∞1!²Qζ'ΣσmHτš]ē«mW±j⅔λg0ω(⅛]z2↑ΦΠ`‰ι6l→φβ$τ─θģX⅝č═ιx‰ωģΓī÷nπ□f⅔‛⁽r←′m╤‛ω=Ƨ°AC╤׀Λι_N№λ;∞Wy׀│Θ|<υ│čθæΣφ`kc_~╥χ╗βV%▒8 }W #`╔i/Φ⁰_⁴¡ŗ»w'h╝¬ζζhψ∞¦≡╝Zοθ ⁾6øuιΦ‰→▒EøG`τΧiι─⁽√═Σ[δ≥K╝χ(┌┘c′ΗΣ&⁹εD){∑⁷ξ─¶rΔo⁄γ┘$∞Xσlr≡κπ▼mΩ)ZΔ~O}░WαP░k⁶C∑θm∫δΔƧI¹¡Μ═yž⁷τ}\■∙‰m‛fTζΒ░√┘↕D/²β-⁄⌠>AλL^pΔαJy»r□⁾№1]¬$2x²└Γ3└2λh≈JjƧōfλΕUυ↓nΥζ⁸Ω\o╚	OIž⁄℮→ΛjšøΩ²+‼q2øæωZx∙n_≤c⁰√┘0Ωσθq⅟OΔ⌠ο⅛╚JK⅓ηļ┘∑O┼Q╥μ┘≤⅛¦χΔEhV┌0⌡ƧνƧžσ┘d∑gø⁽z2:>θæDēYΜ3Θ≤B9NznjWΣΦ`Ƨ∞⅜▲¤Β‚[⁸σ[%q²≤C℮↕│→═oqΕΕ⅟╔¦←sgοč∆ΥM⅓l=‼Νg‚ū⁾Ρ⁶└φOÆi░─Æ█P‛ŗ‼r¡⁰{Ƨ,»▼▓-¤ζ0u%□→Θ▲φιp<8γ■■»ƨ0āροηp>9m┐⅓M█σsζTl▲č↕η∫æΣ`╗ņ%Ι'¼Tn⁽¤5iž■▼š○g∞κ■⁄Y⅔Θ§y⅜▼╥¬[χζθη╥μƧ¤█I,ιƧķ\ε(¹Δ▼⁷θ▓	Γ≠EJ≡c‼+j⁸γpφņ⁽╚⁵≠BķGαE.Ο>┼ōZ‽r¶ΓΨ√↕,=↔⅜δδ∑№γ3ε │ņγ≈OzY^)⁹CΥ[′I′╤¾½z³←‰V∆t≠χΘø⅞/f▒⁶Κ*ξeν‼⁄ēa▒Π¾Π{PUΦ<⁶┘Χ⁰ģΘ┼ķ(ƧΒƨC√≥→■╔u∆F┼h“šιο:|Oρ÷	)≤iζŗof~Gø8;Θ¦╝┐@ā%GXυMλ┘∙ķoωαΕ≥▲5s℮½׀v¼╬æ4θ9XG⌡ΙΖuΞPSλ⁷7⅜³Ζ∑ΚΧ¼Ι‼→`⁽PΨ:δZ§∙▓«ο∑»η@l═ģ~ƨty¬8Γ¾.⁷f]lΥ¬l?⁵η⌡0Γ÷|°▓8┘]υ°'ψ÷ū7²īHø ⁾p⅓Wα■zΞ¹→ļsæZ¼ΦΝ5.a╤χqi⅝⌡←'\k[η═‼āΖK¬c§ķ⁽β⅔═ļ!O3▲⁸◄-∆ΜhS▒ģgΘ○ν≠OmV'║░∫κΒ¬č¤L⅝‚U½‰\¾¾░∫Ε╥ƨ┼KΣ»$Ii┐┌Swb↓Ι(;ξν׀▓Φ▒Εyη│׀L►¤Χ8°№IΦb]┌─┐⁴λv;¾╔+/Χ,┐┼½∫`9»Ι⁶←<ρg╔Θī[?ΧƧωΣ▓ŗ(.?Ξ╥P⁸ÆžH│⅓≤╚ī┘⁹u~¤²τj╝∫^7∙η0׀wΞd↓⁹4¶ζρø╬1≤⅔@\GΞ9ŗXζ¾≈⁴sΠoēHļ¶η¡hļņ√ōρq3κT┘W}'α■׀pī►aυ±▒ι┐τΥ▒⅝⁾┘⁵⌡YēbA⅓P↔⁶T\⅟≥Σ═ƨΣρ-K_)κδ⅟⅝J⁹Mρ;Κ⅞¬K⁹½?øh{x┘HζΞ:pzG¦μΞILοM{πA╗1ωχ┐≥█fv?╗┌⌡½╝↔Ež‚│~ƧQ¹Θ⅜§oφ►AƨΛ○#ŗ√┌²ø┘≥‛׀#(‰╔±ΧrnK[׀μ¤&z‘o5─r∑"-+<>.”{ē;ŗ}o"ģ#ģ⁸ƨJΕ\f╬-⁴↕ΘιPΒ¾G¶[}⅞■X∙κΕφ■3U~ņšīU╬↓;W⌠Ji`]¤Ƨ╝0¼¦⅜ηoε≡³φ}¹→«π╔ΤøηWb=18?¡○Κ┐ Ι→dΒ-k⌡τΚ)Ιrqy¤─οΛ℮⁴¹$~dā└	+Zŗ℮⅓ī□Z⁷┌øaΩ┌δb╚ο¼Ψ*c─Δ∞¬ēJZū─Ωq┘‽+³⅟¶⅟‽¬bmχ¶╥╗┌½%ģIō}⅞|»²Φ}2νΧ⁷h╤.⅛k)ψΥ⅛ρP±↓*Hfī⅞γN■Zž⁶Eθc⅞ωNq&r³⅜Οæ¼Ω⁾jdc⁶⁶╝ΘƧ◄ρ):▒½q2y═@p⌡mδ¹ƨ1‚+⅜π′∑┼░!0≥Λ7nD³ņ⁰@dķ⌠Ψāt6ģ►┼P>⅛nκ|←Ψķ÷g2Ƨ³3*∞!d3#KY→▲#‚⁾u⌡{⌡Wθ≥⅛Q	╗	7⅓↓P°√ΒD┼⁴╔⁴Εψ°╬οy~ξφ◄↑ν¾↔,ķ'►:◄Π′<ā⁸‛↕bΩξΖ(¼IXh╬▒╗λ»Ψf.6{5§⁵\℮‛Ƨž▒JψR≡ΧΓOKρoε■⁶²~⅔∆ε√Π7⁾ƨķ9□↑ø¡θ8sΟ▲]/ļυ<⁄νφWŗ◄>tqI⅔*≈ΥωΗγN²ΖqΟf┘⁽§γ-W◄ε┼~═Ρ/P╚=η⅟√κ¦Mc∞C≠L¾x⁸ū^³≡≡§`⁹j←τφ¡γΒ‼H═ωΝ─Φ⌠@τνA╤ī┼9░]ρ╚Q>ωΙ╝a¼2Γ↕┼σ³)○ņΦē≡D┼=Dm{ģ∞.Φ|l←ƧΤ8^Yv~┐└M)T⁽∑ļ)⅓d~⁷◄Λ6^⅝Hæi∞׀ē_Ψξŗ█└■Κ⁄═rΡ1ūΝΥλ≈ņ.-{jVFy!⁹κ9kΦδ⁴_/r╔⅟ρ%÷χ№┌τε╬→q/ƧΔ║ο<∑Ƨθ$ν≠√r°⅔∆≥Ylæ:─=ζR¼÷Zκb╤÷σ$ķφpš`0↕√{δ*║.KIu|b∑+Δ⌠{Σ,οPX4№[F[⅓⅓ν׀C³Æψ(█░xx¶ΝK1÷δt←┼─┐↔ķ4χψ;GβJ│⁵α÷κδ⅛{(«′F4≠θ◄95└(]Β┼}─`1«׀⁶Κ↓▲č&ΟqΧ¶6▼87$Ν8DBY`υoγ{r╚█└‽hψΠ:aLψΗ⌡≤hΜ℮═]θT⌠I─GΧŗ⅔(╔⅞H▼]ΩAk○žEΡy⅞*x‚½◄/╗⅟Β%F+q5ķΩ,─↕ič℮\cΥΕ&6⅔Ky⅓׀7≠V⁶wi_Xc&╔x*q96‚δ■ī∫┐↓8⅟Xņ,ī─⁄∞λcJοFη▓÷ ⁽ξ¤±|⁴pι╚╬‛i∑↓J?Μ=Æ&ņ∫┐ƨΖ]=┌V׀{(?c`χ√░3∑wƧ¦q~′§o∫Z′HB⁰Ƨ∞nģt⁽≈ΠL⁸⌠░[@20∫≤R↓⌡¹⌡č╥π⁷‘o
```

Try it on [here](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/) (no SOGL permalink because it's too long). Warning: takes a loooong time to run because SOGL is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

## 30. Java 10, [1780676 bytes](https://s18.postimg.cc/sed8qz8qh/Capture.png)

```java
v->{var b=new java.math.BigInteger("X");for(;!b.equals(b.ZERO);b=b.subtract(b.ONE))System.out.print(0);}
```

With `X` replaced by the number in [*@hakr14*'s link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XMH7hmKZZb/plain/).

No TIO link, because the link is too long to fit in this answer (1,116,442 characters), and URL shorteners are crashing.. >.>

Hmm, I think my score should be quite high..

Comment: this one wins the challenge

Comment: no point in continuing

Comment: Your length seems incorrect

Comment: @mbomb007 It's useless to say you "don't want to cheat the scoring system", it comes sooner or later

Comment: @KevinCruijssen How is your code 1548511 bytes while you pasted a 1780574 bytes number in it?

Comment: I already know what went wrong this time (number wasn't fully loaded when I copied it..). But my initial byte-count of 1,780,676 is correct. Not sure why you said the length seems incorrect in your previous comment.

Comment: ```'v->{var b=new java.math.BigInteger("");for(;!b.equals(b.ZERO);b=b.subtract(b.ONE))System.out.print(0);}'.length+1780574 = 1780677```

Comment: @l4m2 When I copy the complete number from _hakr14_'s link it's [1,780,573 digits/bytes](https://s18.postimg.cc/cgbgqrg5l/1780573_bytes.png).. Not sure where your byte comes from.. Maybe you had a trailing new-line or something?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You are right. If so the byte count of 29 is wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

## 8. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 179 bytes

```
•y˜Çr-ñāt¿&ãx^ÇlBËÔáA∊z^a’Ù;Ò êþ2¤´ñ¡ηjƒĆαs½ζ!é/‰.*<œéÊŒfº}ÎjþŒ1ø–Îи:tÂβιne‘ʒÒƒŒNyÕ9îK<ÊýÇM∞iº§ΘT]µ¯šÍθβ©X#ûÿ±7SÝ`0ð_oPw°<G¶¦L“LJoN¨₁A+Ù¨ðè›eÞfRÃkδÑ)©vC‚λB₂Á©Bí²W>ÝÅιµн'sÍ¦•254вçJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DdDdSsJgHAfgWymCoqJSSaKSQDsIzCIqqJMsA4UsElIqg2AuSjEUmgUaKlihLqi2oeYHKvx/zoOCF6/hvZHVcwmPyeo5NHsNgwsv4d8somdTUHuREHVH8XrpRvTEgXs8omDnsfiV28OFDDKLkIbwjo6F3qgClQrs29@XendMDVKb1YYhz3BBmZ6w6SnIiOuSj5rXSPrR0SUz6lxIITmoL4QgMo01Tr1cSP9IkPqSLq2H8TSPz1Ub4mgjusZj@SNqUomlt/eoSl96AQlWZxrJuyNooUvq3BZyByYo@4GNC1JsK1SjoosLWZczsE5lLkbsk8hQGQrKXGh6kfdt4uaYVfAwTvL5MheeWcvBRRERkh34IG1nCTncsgZVB@2xIBJU/L@xWGcHGkpOw/gD)

30 bytes less<sup>1</sup> than the last submission, by using the 05AB1E [codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage).

<sup><sup>1</sup>Because saying "shorter" seems way too unfit when it isn't readily apparent by the character count.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## 21. [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22042 bytes

```
  		4* 	 ¶   	 	 			¶  		 		 	¶   	 	 ¶   4*	   	  	  ¶   	 	  ¶   			4* 	 ¶   	  	  		 ¶  		 			 ¶   	8* 		 	 ¶  4*	 		¶   	   	 			¶   			 		 	5* ¶  		4* 		¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   	7* 	 ¶   		¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   4*	 	¶   	 		  	¶  		   	 ¶   	  	 4*	¶   	 		 		¶   	5* 		 	¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  		 			¶   		  		 	¶   		   		¶  		6* ¶   4*	  		  			¶   4*	 4*	¶   4*	   	 4*	¶   			 			  			 ¶  		 		 	¶   			 			 			  ¶   	4* ¶  		  ¶   	 		¶   4*	5* 	   ¶  6*	 ¶   			 			  			 ¶  		  		¶  		  ¶   	   	 	¶   			 ¶  		5* ¶   	 			¶  		 ¶   		   	 ¶  		4* 	¶  		 	 		¶   			4* 		¶  			¶   4*	 	¶   	6* 	  	   ¶  			 	 ¶   	  			 ¶   			4* 	 ¶   	  		 	  ¶  			  ¶   		   		¶  			 		¶   			 			  			 ¶   			 			  4*	¶   4*	   4*	  ¶   	  	 4*	¶   	5* 		¶   			 7*	 	¶   		   ¶   	8* 		  	¶   	 ¶   4*	 		¶   	   	 	¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	  	 	 ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   		 	¶   	 		  	 ¶4* ¶   			 7*	 	¶   		   ¶   			 5*	 			¶   	 	 ¶   	  	 			 ¶   4*	5* 	  	¶  			  	 ¶   	 		  		¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   			 		 5*	 ¶  		   		¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   	4* ¶   	   		   ¶   			 			6* ¶   			 		  5*	¶   		 		 	¶   	  	  		¶   	  	   		¶   			 			 			  ¶  		 	¶   	8* 	4* ¶  5*	 	¶   	  			 ¶   7*	  ¶   	 	5* 	¶  		5* 	¶   	   	 			¶   	5* 	 ¶   			 	  		¶   			 			 			  ¶   			 7*	 	¶  		 	  ¶  5*	¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	 	  	   ¶  		  ¶   4*	  		 	  	¶  4*	 	¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶  		6* ¶   6*	 			   ¶   6*	 		 	 	¶   4*	5* 	   ¶   	 	 ¶   5*	  		¶   4*	 	¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   			 	  ¶   	7* 	 ¶  		   ¶  		   ¶  		6* ¶   			 		 			 		¶   	 	  	 ¶   	  	   ¶   	   		   ¶   4*	5* 	   ¶   	5* 	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   4*	  	 	 	  ¶   	   	  			¶   	   		   ¶   4*	   	 4*	¶   	 		¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   4*	6* 		 ¶   	  	  		¶  		 		  ¶  		   	  ¶   	8* 	   	¶  		4* 		¶   			 	  		¶   		 	¶  			  ¶  			¶   4*	   	   		¶   	  			 ¶   			 		 	  		 ¶   	 	  	  	¶  		 	 	 ¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   			4* 		¶   7*	  ¶  4*	   ¶   	8* 	  		¶  6*	¶   	 	  			¶   	 4*	  ¶   	4* 	 ¶   4*	 	 ¶   	  		¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   			 4*	   		¶  		 	 ¶   	 	 	¶   4*	5* 	   ¶  		 4*	¶  		 	¶  		 	   ¶   		 		  ¶   			  	 		¶   			 5*	  		¶   		  ¶   4*	 	7* ¶   			 4*	   	 ¶   4*	   	  		 ¶  		4* 		¶   			 5*	 		 ¶  6*	¶   			6* ¶   4*	 	 ¶  5*	 	¶   4*	 	 ¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   	  	 		 	¶  		   		¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  		  	  ¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   	  	 ¶   			 ¶   			 7*	  ¶   	 	  	  	¶   			 			5* 	¶   	  	 	  ¶  			 	 ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶  		6* ¶   	  	 		 	¶   	   		  ¶   4*	   	  			¶   			 		  5*	¶   	   	¶   	   	 	¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   	 	¶   		 			  ¶   			 9*	¶   	  	 4*	¶   		   ¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   	   4*	  ¶  			 	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶  4*	¶  5*	¶   	  		 	  ¶   			  	 	 ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	5* 	 ¶   	  	   		¶  		 	 ¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   		   	 ¶  		 	 		¶   	  	¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   4*	 	 ¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   	6* 	  	   ¶   	  		¶   	8* 	 			¶   			 		 	  			¶   	 	 	 	¶   			4* 	 ¶  5*	 	¶   	   		   ¶  			   	¶   5*	 ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶  6*	¶   	   	¶   		 		 	¶  6*	 ¶   		 		  ¶   	6* 	  	   ¶   			 8*	 ¶   	 	  	   ¶   	  	 ¶  			 	 ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	  			 ¶  			  	¶  			  	¶  		 			¶  4*	  ¶   			 5*	  		¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶   	7* 	 ¶   4*	  		  			¶   			 4*	   		¶  		 		  ¶  			 ¶   			 			 	  	 ¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   			 4*	   		¶   		 			  ¶   	6* 	  	   ¶  			 ¶   			 			  			 ¶  		 			 ¶   	  	 			 ¶   	  	¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶  		 	   ¶  			   	¶  4*	  	¶   4*	   	 			 ¶  		 4*	¶   			 8*	 ¶   		 ¶   4*	  	 	 	  ¶   			  	 		¶   			 7*	 	¶   	   	  			¶   			 			  4*	¶  			 			¶   			 4*	   		¶   		 		 		¶   			 9*	¶   			 			  4*	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   	 	   	¶  			   	¶  4*	 	¶   			5* 	¶   	  	   ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   			 		 			 		¶  		 		¶  4*	  	¶   			 		 	  		 ¶   5*	  		¶   	 		  	¶  4*	 	 ¶  		 		 	¶  5*	 	¶   			 			5* 	¶   4*	 		¶   	4* 		   ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶  			 ¶   		  		  ¶  		4* ¶   			  		¶   	   4*	  ¶  			 	¶   4*	 	 ¶   	  4*	¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   	  	  	  ¶  		   		¶   			 		 6*	¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   			6* ¶   4*	   	  			¶   	  	 ¶   	 		  	 ¶   	8* 	 			¶   		  		  ¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  		 		  ¶   			 			 	  	 ¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  4*	 	 ¶  		 		 ¶   	8* 		 	 ¶  		 			 ¶  		  	 	¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	 		 		¶   		   ¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   	4* 	 ¶   	   	  			¶   	8* 		 	 ¶  			¶   			 5*	  	 ¶  		 	  	¶   4*	 	7* ¶   	 ¶   	4* 		   ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶  4*	 	 ¶  		  		 ¶   	 4*	 	¶   	8* 	 	 	¶   	¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   	8* 	  		¶   	 		 		¶   	  	  	  ¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   	 	   	¶   	   		   ¶  		   	 ¶  4*	  ¶  			 	¶  4*	 	¶   		 			  ¶   		 		  ¶   	 		 		¶   	 4*	  ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   			 8*	 ¶  		 	 		¶   	 	 	 	¶  		   	¶   	   4*	  ¶  		¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶   4*	   	   		¶   			 		 6*	¶   	8* 	   	¶   4*	¶   			 4*	5* ¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶  4*	 		¶   	  		 	  ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   			 	  ¶   	 	  		 ¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   	  	 	 ¶  			 	  ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶  		  	¶  			 ¶   		  		 	¶  		6* ¶   	  		 	 	¶   6*	¶   			  		¶   			 			6* ¶   5*	  		¶   			 8*	 ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶   			 			 			 	¶   4*	   	   		¶  		   	  ¶   			 			 ¶   	5* 		¶   	8* 	  		¶   	   			 	¶  		   	 ¶   			4* 	 ¶   			  	 	 ¶  		  	 	¶   	¶   	  		 	  ¶  			 			¶   4*	  		  		 ¶  		   		¶   			 		 	4* 	¶  			 			¶   	 	6* ¶   		 		 	¶   			 7*	 	¶   		  ¶   	 	  			 ¶  		  	 ¶   		   		¶   	4* 	 ¶   4*	4* 		 		¶   	 	  		 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   	   		   ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   	   ¶   	  		 	 ¶  4*	  ¶   	  	 ¶   	  	  		 ¶   	5* 			 ¶   		   		¶   	5* 		¶  		   		¶   			 		 			 	 ¶   		¶   	  			 ¶  			  		¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	 	¶   5*	 ¶  		  	¶   4*	   	 			 ¶  		 4*	¶   	  	 	  ¶   			 			 5*	¶   	5* 		 	¶  4*	¶   			 5*	 			¶  		4* 	¶   			 9*	¶  5*	 	¶   		¶  6*	¶  		 	  	¶  			  	 ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	5* 			 ¶   4*	4* 		 		¶  			 	 	¶   			 4*	4* 	¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   			 5*	  	 ¶  		6* ¶   	   4*	  ¶  		 			 ¶   			 			5* 	¶   4*	 	¶   			 		 5*	 ¶   	  4*	¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   	   4*	  ¶   			 			 			  ¶   	  	 4*	¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  			  	¶   	4* 	 ¶  			  	 ¶   			 			  4*	¶  		  	  ¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   			4* 	 ¶   	8* 	 	 	¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   			4* 		¶   	   ¶   	 	5* 	¶   	   ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   4*	6* 			¶   	 	 	 	¶   	  		  ¶   			 			 	  		¶   4*	6* 			¶  		   	 ¶  		4* 		¶   			 			  			 ¶  		  	 	¶  		  		¶   	 ¶   	  		 	 	¶  			  ¶   			 		 	  			¶   			 		 6*	¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   4*	¶   	  		 	 	¶   			¶   			 			 4*	 ¶  		 	 	¶   	 4*	 	¶   			 			 			  ¶   	   	 			¶   4*	6* 			¶   	  	  	  ¶   			 			  			 ¶   		¶   			 5*	  		¶   		   		¶   			¶   			6* ¶  6*	 ¶   4*	   	  	  ¶   	5* 			 ¶  			   ¶   	   		  ¶   	4* 	 ¶   	   	 	¶   			 			 			  ¶  		 		  ¶  4*	  ¶   			6* ¶   	5* 		¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   	   			 	¶   			 			 			 	¶  6*	¶   		  		  ¶  		  		¶  		   	  ¶   4*	   	 	 		¶  		 			 ¶   4*	   	   	 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶  			 		¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	  	¶  		  	 ¶   	4* ¶   	8* 	  		¶  7*	¶   4*	 		¶   	 4*	 	¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   	 	  	   ¶   			 5*	 			¶  			  	 ¶   	 		  		¶   			 			 			  ¶   	  	 		 	¶  		  	 	¶   			 			 5*	¶  			 		¶4* ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  		   	 ¶   			 		 6*	¶   			  	 		¶   			6* ¶   4*	¶   			 			 			 	¶   		 	¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   	 		  	¶  		 		 ¶   	   	¶   	5* 		¶  			  	 ¶  4*	¶   			¶   			 8*	 ¶   	  		 	 	¶   	 	5* 	¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶   	 	 ¶   			 5*	 		 ¶  6*	¶   	   			 	¶   			 			 ¶   			 		 			 	 ¶   	   	¶   7*	  ¶   5*	  		¶  		 	 ¶  		 	 		¶   			 		  5*	¶  		 	 	¶   	  		¶   	 		 		¶   4*	   	  	 	¶  		 	 	 ¶   	8* 	  		¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   			 ¶  4*	  ¶  4*	¶   			 		 	  		 ¶   	 	 ¶  4*	 ¶  4*	¶  		  	 	¶  		5* 	¶   	 4*	  ¶   	8* 	   	¶   	 	  		 ¶  		  	 ¶   	   ¶  		 	¶  7*	¶   	 	  	 ¶   	4* 	 ¶  		  	¶   			 			 4*	 ¶   			 		  4*	 ¶  		   	¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   	  	 			 ¶   	5* 		¶  		 	 		¶   	  		  ¶   	  		  ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶  			  	¶   	   	 	¶   			  	 	 ¶   5*	  		¶   	   4*	  ¶  			 			¶   	 ¶   	   	  			¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶  		 4*	¶   	8* 	   	¶  			 	 ¶  		 			 ¶   	 		  	¶   7*	  ¶   			 		 			 		¶  5*	¶   		 			  ¶  		4* 	¶  			 	¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶  4*	 	 ¶   		   		¶   	 			¶   4*	6* 			¶  		   		¶   			 5*	  		¶   	  	   ¶   	   			 	¶   	8* 	  	 ¶  		   	¶   4*	 	 ¶   	 		  		¶   	  	 	 ¶   			 			 5*	¶   	   		   ¶   			 			6* ¶   	 	  ¶   			 9*	¶   			 	  		¶   	  		 	 ¶   	  	  		 ¶   			 7*	  ¶   			 			  4*	¶   	  	¶   	8* 		   ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   4*	   	  			¶   			 			 4*	 ¶   	  		 	  ¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   			4* 	 ¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   		  		  ¶   			 		 	  			¶   			 		 	4* 	¶  4*	¶   4*	 	 ¶   	4* ¶  			  	¶  		   	¶   	 		  		¶   4*	  		  		 ¶   		 ¶   	8* 	  		¶   4*	   4*	 	¶  		¶  		   	  ¶  			 	 	¶   4*	   	  			¶  		 			 ¶   	  ¶   	 	5* 	¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶   			 4*	   		¶  		  			¶   	4* ¶   			 5*	 			¶   		 	 ¶   			5* 	¶   			 			 ¶   	 	  			 ¶  		 	   ¶  6*	 ¶  			 	 ¶   	 	 	 	¶   4*	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶  5*	  ¶  		 	   ¶  		5* 	¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   	  ¶   			¶   		  	¶  6*	 ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   4*	 		¶   	 			¶   	  4*	¶   	  	 	 ¶  4*	  	¶   		  	¶  		  	 	¶   			 			 			  ¶  			   ¶   	   	  			¶   		 ¶  		  		¶  		4* 	¶   			 		 5*	 ¶   		¶   			 	  ¶  			  		¶   4*	5* 	   ¶   	 		¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   	  	 4*	¶   	  4*	¶  			  	 ¶   			  	 	 ¶   	   ¶  		5* ¶   	7* 	 ¶   	 		¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶  4*	  	¶   			 		 6*	¶  		 4*	¶   4*	  		  			¶  		   		¶  		 			¶   			 			 			 	¶   	  	 			 ¶   	 	  ¶   	5* 	¶  		  	 	¶   	  	  		¶   	8* 		   ¶   	 	  	  	¶   	  	   ¶  		  	 ¶4* ¶   			 		 			 		¶   	   	 			¶   			 			 			 	¶   			¶  			 		¶   			¶   4*	 	6* 	¶  		 			 ¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   	  	  		¶  		 	¶   	5* 	¶   	  		  ¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   4*	¶   	  	 4*	¶   			 7*	  ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶   			 			 	  		¶   	 4*	 	¶   			 4*	   		¶   	  	 4*	¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   			  	 		¶  6*	 ¶   	 		  	 ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶  		   	 ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶  4*	  ¶   	  	 		 	¶4* ¶   4*	   	  			¶   	 	  			 ¶   			  		¶  		 	   ¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   	  		 	 	¶  		  	  ¶   	  	 ¶  			  	 ¶   	 		 		¶   	 		  	¶   	5* 		¶   			 9*	¶  4*	 		¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		 		¶   	 			¶   	 	  	   ¶   	  	  		 ¶   	5* 	¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   	¶   	5* 	¶   	  	  		¶  			 		¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶  			  	¶   	  	   		¶   6*	¶   	   	 	¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   			 	  		¶   4*	4* 		 		¶   	   		   ¶   			 7*	  ¶   	8* 	 			¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   			  		¶   5*	 ¶   4*	6* 			¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   			 		 	 	  	¶  		   	  ¶   	  	  		¶   			 5*	  		¶   	¶   	   4*	  ¶   	 	  	 ¶  		 	 	¶   		 			  ¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶   	  	   		¶   	 		  	 ¶   	  	  	  ¶   			 4*	5* ¶   			 		 	  			¶   	  	 	  ¶  		¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   4*	   	   		¶   			 4*	¶   		  ¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   	8* 	   	¶   			 		 			 		¶   		   		¶  			  		¶   	 		  	 ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   	  	¶   4*	5* 	  	¶   	  	 ¶  		6* ¶  		4* 		¶   	 	  	  	¶   	   4*	  ¶   			 ¶   			 4*	   		¶   4*	  	 	 	  ¶   4*	 	¶   			 		 	5* ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   4*	   	   		¶   	 	  	   ¶   	 	  			 ¶  7*	¶  7*	¶  6*	 ¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   	  ¶   		  		 	¶   4*	   	   	 ¶   4*	¶  		 	 		¶   			 			5* 	¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  6*	 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶  		   	 ¶   4*	5* 	  	¶   			 8*	 ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶  			 			¶   	  		¶  5*	 	¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   		  ¶   			  		¶   			 			 	  		¶   	  		 	 	¶   4*	6* 		 ¶   	 	  			 ¶   	 	  	  	¶   		   	 ¶   	 	   	¶   	  			  	¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   		 		  ¶   		  ¶   	   		  ¶   	8* 	4* ¶  			 	 ¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   		 	¶  4*	  ¶  4*	  	¶   	   		  ¶   	 	  		 ¶   		¶   	   4*	  ¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   	4* ¶   		  		  ¶  		 4*	¶   		 			  ¶  		4* ¶  		4* 		¶   	 	 ¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶  		 		  ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   4*	 	¶   	   ¶  			  	 ¶   			 		 	5* ¶   			 		  5*	¶  			   	¶   		¶   	 		  	 ¶  		   	 ¶  		5* ¶  		 	  ¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶   			 		 5*	 ¶   	 	5* 	¶   4*	   	  	 	¶  		  	 ¶   			4* 	 ¶   	 		  	¶  		  			¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶  		  ¶   		  ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  		   	¶  		 			 ¶   	8* 		  	¶  		 			 ¶  		 		¶   4*	  		  			¶   4*	  		  			¶   	4* 	 ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   	 	  	 ¶  		 		  ¶  		 			 ¶  		  ¶  4*	  	¶   		  ¶   	 			¶   			 5*	 			¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   			  		¶  		 		 	¶   			 			 4*	 ¶   	   	 	¶   4*	   	 4*	¶   	   	 			¶   	   		   ¶  		 		¶   	  	 		 	¶   			  	 	 ¶   			 5*	  		¶   	5* 	¶   	  ¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   	 	  			¶   4*	 	¶   6*	¶   		   		¶  5*	 	¶   			 		 			 		¶  		 		 ¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	 	  	   ¶   	 	  		 ¶  		   	 ¶   	  	   ¶  		 	  	¶   			 		 			 		¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	 	 	 	¶   6*	¶   		 ¶  		 		 	¶  		 			 ¶   			 4*	   	 ¶   		¶  		  		¶  			  	¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   			 ¶  		  		 ¶  4*	¶   			 			5* 	¶   5*	 ¶   			 			 			 	¶  		 	   ¶  		  		 ¶   			 5*	 		 ¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   4*	  	 	 	  ¶  		   	  ¶   	8* 	  		¶  		 		  ¶  			  ¶   			 			5* 	¶   		  		 	¶   	 	  		 ¶  		   	 ¶  		  ¶   	  		  ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶  			   ¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	   4*	  ¶  		5* ¶   4*	   	  	 	¶  		  		¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   	  	   ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶   			 			 	  	 ¶   			 		 5*	 ¶   			 9*	¶   4*	  		  			¶   	4* 		   ¶   4*	   	  			¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   	4* 		   ¶  			 ¶   			 5*	  	 ¶  		   	¶   	8* 		  	¶   			 4*	¶   	   	  			¶   			 			 4*	 ¶   	   	 			¶  		 	  ¶   	 ¶  		4* 	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   	 ¶   4*	   	 	 		¶  5*	 ¶   		 	¶   			 		 			 		¶   			 			6* ¶  			 			¶   		   		¶   	 	5* 	¶   			 7*	 	¶  		 	 ¶   	  	 	  ¶  4*	 	¶   	   			 	¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   			 8*	 ¶   			 5*	  	 ¶   	  	 	 ¶   			 8*	 ¶   4*	5* 	  	¶  4*	  ¶   4*	   	   	 ¶  		 	 ¶   4*	5* 	   ¶  		 	  ¶  		 	   ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶   			 7*	  ¶  		   	¶   		 ¶   			 			 ¶   			  		¶   4*	   	  	 	¶  		 	 		¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   7*	  ¶  5*	  ¶  		¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   		  		  ¶   			  	 	 ¶   			 		 			 	 ¶   	 			¶  5*	 ¶   	 		 ¶   	5* 		 	¶  		 		¶  		 	   ¶   			4* 		¶  4*	 	 ¶  		 	   ¶   	6* ¶  		¶   4*	   	 			 ¶  		  	¶   			 	  		¶  			 			¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   	 ¶   4*	 	¶  			  ¶   	  	  		¶   4*	  		  			¶   5*	 ¶   4*	  		  			¶   	 	   	¶   			 		 			 		¶   			 			 ¶   	   	  			¶   			  		¶   6*	¶   	8* 		 	 ¶  		 	 	 ¶   	  		¶  			¶   		  ¶   	 	 	 	¶   	 		  		¶  			   ¶   4*	   	  	  ¶   	 			¶  		  	  ¶   			4* 		¶   		   	 ¶   	   	 	¶  		  	  ¶   			 7*	  ¶   	8* 	  		¶   4*	 	7* ¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   			 4*	¶  		5* ¶   4*	   	  	  ¶   	  		  ¶   4*	¶   	¶   			 7*	 	¶   		 		  ¶   	  		¶   	 		¶   			 		 	  			¶   	  		¶   4*	6* 		 ¶   	5* 		 	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   		  	¶   			 			  4*	¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   	   		  ¶   			 4*	¶   			 			 			  ¶   	8* 	   	¶   			 			  			 ¶  			 	 ¶   	   		 	¶   	  			  	¶  		4* 	¶   	   			 	¶  		  		¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   		  	¶   		 		 	¶   	 		 		¶  			 		 ¶  			 		 ¶  		  ¶  5*	¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶   			 8*	 ¶   			 	  ¶   	  	 ¶  		 			¶   	6* 	  	   ¶   	5* 		 	¶  4*	 	¶   			 ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶  4*	  ¶  4*	¶  		   	¶  			 	  ¶   4*	 	7* ¶   			 5*	 			¶   			 7*	 	¶  		  			¶   	 		  	 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   	 	 	 	¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   			 			 	  		¶   		 	 ¶   4*	  		  		 ¶  			4* ¶   	5* 		¶   	8* 	 	 	¶   		   	 ¶   			 8*	 ¶   	4* ¶  			 ¶   			 7*	  ¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   			 	  ¶  4*	 		¶  		 	 		¶   	8* 	   	¶   	4* 		   ¶   	  ¶   	  	 	  ¶   			 7*	  ¶   	 	¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   		 			  ¶  4*	 	¶   			 		 	5* ¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   			 5*	  		¶   	8* 	 	 	¶   			 ¶  			  	 ¶   	  		¶   	4* ¶   		 		  ¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   	  		 	  ¶   			 7*	 	¶   	 	 	 	¶   	  		 	 ¶   			 		 5*	 ¶   	  	  		 ¶  4*	 	¶  		 	¶   4*	  		  		 ¶   	 	  			¶  		  	  ¶  6*	 ¶   	 	   	¶  		  	¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   	   			 	¶   			6* ¶   	8* 		   ¶   4*	 		¶   	   	 			¶   	 	   	¶   			4* 		¶  4*	 		¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  5*	 ¶  			  	¶   			 			  			 ¶   	  	¶   			 			5* 	¶   	 		  		¶   		  		  ¶   			 4*	5* ¶   			 5*	 		 ¶   	4* 	 ¶   	   		  ¶   	  		 	 ¶   	  	 	 ¶  		 	   ¶  			 			¶   	  	¶   	6* ¶  4*	 	 ¶   	 	  		 ¶   	 		 		¶  		  	  ¶   			 			 	  	 ¶  4*	   ¶   	  		¶   	¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		  		 ¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   4*	5* 	  	¶   	 	  	 ¶   	   	 	¶   			 	  ¶   			 			  			 ¶   		 	¶   			 		 	5* ¶  			 	 ¶   		 		 	¶   4*	 	 ¶   	  	 		 	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶  		 ¶   	  ¶  		 ¶  		 		 	¶   	5* 		 	¶   	8* 	   	¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶   			4* 		¶   	   	 			¶   		   		¶   	  		 	 	¶  			 ¶  		 			¶  		4* 		¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   4*	   	   	 ¶   		¶   4*	   	  			¶   			 7*	  ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   	  	¶   4*	 	 ¶   	  ¶  		 		¶   5*	 ¶  			  		¶   	  	 		 	¶   4*	   	  			¶   			 5*	 		 ¶   4*	  		  			¶   			4* 		¶   4*	5* 	  	¶   4*	   4*	  ¶   	 		  	¶   			 	  ¶  		 4*	¶   	 ¶  		   	  ¶   			 			 	  		¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   		 	 ¶   	 	  			¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		  ¶   	4* 	 ¶   	 		 		¶   4*	 	  	   	¶  		   	¶   	6* ¶   	  	¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶   	6* 	  	   ¶  6*	 ¶   	 		  	 ¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   	 			¶   		  ¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   		   	 ¶  			 		¶   	6* ¶   	  	 4*	¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   	4* ¶   	  	   ¶   	 	 	¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   	 	  	   ¶  		   	 ¶   	   	 	¶   			5* 	¶   		  	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   			 9*	¶  4*	  ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶  			 		 ¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶  		 	  ¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   			 			  4*	¶   	  	 			 ¶   		   		¶   			 7*	  ¶   	 	 	 	¶  			 			¶   	 	  			¶   	 		6* 	 	 ¶   			 			  4*	¶   	  ¶   		 		  ¶  		 	 	¶  			 ¶   4*	   	   	 ¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   4*	   	   		¶  4*	 		¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   4*	  		  			¶   4*	5* 	  	¶   	6* 	  	   ¶   	  	 4*	¶   			 			  4*	¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   4*	   	   		¶   4*	  		 	  	¶  			4* ¶  		 	¶   			 			5* 	¶   		 		  ¶   		  	¶   4*	  		  			¶   			 	  		¶   	 	  	   ¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶  7*	¶   	8* 	   	¶   			 			 ¶   			 5*	  		¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶   	 		  	¶  5*	 	¶   	  			  	¶  			 		 ¶   	  	 4*	¶   		 		 	¶   			 			 5*	¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   	 ¶  		  ¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   	  4*	¶   	5* 		 	¶   	  		 	 ¶  		 	 	¶   4*	   	  	 	¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   5*	  		¶  			  		¶   4*	   	  			¶  			 	¶   			 7*	 	¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   		  		  ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   			 5*	  		¶  4*	¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   			 4*	   		¶   	5* 			 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   4*	   	   		¶   			 		 6*	¶   	 			¶  		 	  ¶   		 			  ¶   	 4*	  ¶   			4* 		¶   		 	¶   7*	  ¶   			 		 	 	  	¶   	 	  		 ¶   			  		¶   4*	 	6* 	¶  			 		 ¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		  	 	¶   			 4*	   	 ¶   4*	  	 	 	  ¶   4*	5* 	   ¶  		  ¶   	  	  		¶   			 	  ¶   	8* 	 	  ¶   			 		 5*	 ¶  4*	 		¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   	 	¶  		  	 ¶  		 	 	 ¶   			 		 	  			¶   			4* 	 ¶   	   			 	¶   	8* 	 		 ¶   4*	¶   		   	 ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   			 8*	 ¶   		   ¶  4*	 		¶   			 			  			 ¶   5*	  		¶   			 7*	  ¶  7*	¶   	5* 	¶   		 		  ¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   	  	 	 ¶   	   		  ¶   	8* 	  		¶  		 	  	¶   4*	 	  	4* ¶  		   	  ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   			 5*	  		¶   			 5*	  		¶   		  		  ¶   4*	  		  			¶  		 4*	¶   	 		  	¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶   4*	6* 		 ¶   			 		 	5* ¶   5*	  		¶   	6* 	  	   ¶  			 	 	¶  4*	   ¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   	 	6* ¶  		 		  ¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   	 		 ¶   			 		 6*	¶   4*	   	  	  ¶  5*	  ¶   		  	¶   			 			5* 	¶   			 			 	  		¶   	 			¶  			 	  ¶   	 	  	  	¶   			¶   			 		 			 		¶   4*	 	  	   	¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  5*	  ¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   4*	   	   		¶  		   		¶   			 			 			 	¶   4*	   	 			 ¶   	8* 	4* ¶   	5* 		 	¶   	 		 		¶   	 		  	 ¶   	  	 ¶   	8* 		  	¶   	5* 			 ¶  			  		¶   4*	   4*	 	¶   	4* 4*	 ¶   	 	  	  	¶  		 	  	¶   	¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		   		¶   	 	6* ¶   			4* 		¶   4*	6* 			¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   		 	¶   			 		 	  		 ¶   			 		 	4* 	¶   	 ¶   			 4*	4* 	¶   5*	 ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶  			   	¶   	 4*	  ¶  		   	¶  		 	   ¶   4*	¶   4*	5* 	  	¶  		 			 ¶   4*	   	  		 ¶   			 		 6*	¶  4*	 	¶   			 7*	 	¶   	 	 ¶  		   	  ¶   4*	  	 	 	 	¶  4*	 	 ¶   			4* 		¶  			 			¶   4*	 	 ¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   	 		  		¶   	   4*	  ¶   	7* 	 ¶   		 		 	¶   			 4*	¶   			 5*	 	  ¶  		  		 ¶   5*	 ¶   	  		 	 	¶  7*	¶   	 		  	 ¶   	5* 	 ¶  			  		¶   	 	   	¶  6*	¶  		4* ¶   			 5*	 	 	¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  		 ¶   	4* 4*	 ¶  		   	 ¶   			 		 	 	   ¶   6*	¶   			 5*	 		 ¶   	   			 	¶   		 	 ¶   		  ¶   6*	¶  			  	¶   4*	   4*	  ¶  4*	 	¶  			 	 	¶   	 ¶   	6* ¶   	 ¶  4*	  	¶   	  4*	¶   		  		 	¶  		 	 		¶   			5* 	¶   			 		 	5* ¶   	   		   ¶   			4* 	 ¶   			 			 4*	 ¶  		 	   ¶   	5* 		 	¶   	   ¶   	   	 	¶   4*	 	  	   	¶  		 	 	 ¶  5*	  ¶   		 		 	¶   			 			  4*	¶   		   ¶   	   		 	¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   4*	4* 		 		¶  4*	  ¶   	  		 	 	¶  		6* ¶  		 			 ¶   			 ¶  		   ¶  		   ¶   			 5*	 			¶   			 			  4*	¶   	 	  			¶   4*	 	 ¶  		  	¶   4*	5* 	  	¶  		  	¶  			 			¶   	  	 	 ¶  		5* 	¶   	8* 	   	¶   5*	 ¶  4*	 	¶  4*	 		¶   	   4*	  ¶   	  	 4*	¶   			 			  4*	¶4* ¶  		  	 	¶   	 	  		 ¶  		 		¶   	  	  	  ¶   	5* 	 ¶   			4* 		¶   4*	   4*	 	¶   	5* 		¶  			 ¶  			 	 	¶   	4* 		   ¶   			  		¶  		6* ¶   			  		¶   	5* 	 ¶   	 	 	 	¶   4*	 	 ¶  		 	   ¶   	8* 	 	 	¶  5*	 	¶  		   	¶   	 			¶   	 	¶  		6* ¶  5*	 ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   ¶   	 	 	 	¶  5*	 	¶   	  	  	  ¶   	  ¶   4*	¶   	6* 	  	   ¶   	5* 			 ¶   4*	4* 		 	 ¶   			 		  4*	 ¶   	  4*	¶  		 	 	¶   	8* 	  	 ¶   4*	6* 		 ¶  4*	   ¶  		5* ¶   4*	   	  	  ¶   	8* 		  	¶   	 	  ¶   		¶  			¶   4*	 	¶   			 4*	   		¶  			  		¶   	 4*	 	¶   			 		 6*	¶   4*	 	7* ¶   	  	   ¶   5*	 ¶  5*	 	¶   	  	 		 	¶   		 			  ¶  		4* ¶   4*	 	6* 	¶   4*	  		 	  	¶   		   		¶   	  		¶   			4* 	 ¶  5*	  ¶  			  	 ¶   			 4*	5* ¶   		 		  ¶   		   		¶   			 		  4*	 ¶  5*	 ¶   6*	 			   ¶  		 	  	¶   	 	 			¶  			   ¶   		  		 	¶   	   		  ¶   	   		 	¶   	  	 4*	¶   	 	5* 	¶   			 			 			  ¶   	  	 ¶   4*	6* 			¶   		 		 		¶  		   		¶   		  		 	¶   	 	  		 ¶   			 			  4*	¶  6*	¶   	  	 ¶   			 		 	5* ¶   4*	   	 4*	¶   			 	  ¶   		 	¶   	 	  	   ¶  		  	¶  		 	 	¶   4*	   	 	 		¶   4*	  		 	   ¶   	 	  			¶  		 			¶   4*	   4*	  ¶  4*	  	¶   4*	   	   	 ¶   	   	  			¶   			 5*	 	  ¶   	 ¶   		  		  ¶   	8* 	  		¶   	6* ¶   	   	 			¶   4*	   	 4*	¶  		   	¶  			  	 ¶   	   	  			¶   	8* 		 	 ¶   	   	¶   4*	   	 	 	 ¶  		4* 	¶   			 			 ¶  		  		 ¶   			 			  4*	¶   	  			  	¶   		¶  		  		¶   			 9*	¶  			   ¶   			 4*	¶   		  	¶   	  	  		 ¶   			 7*	  ¶   		  ¶  		   	 ¶  		 		 	¶   			 		  5*	¶   	  			 ¶   	   			 	¶   	 	  		 ¶   6*	 			   ¶  		4* 	 ¶  		   	  ¶   	¶   	4* ¶   	 	¶   			 ¶   	  		¶  			 		 ¶   	4* ¶   	   	¶   	 		¶4* ¶   	4* ¶   4*	¶  			 		 ¶   4*	¶   4*	¶   	¶  		¶   	 		¶   			 ¶   		  ¶¶  ¶   		  	  ¶	   	¶  ¶ ¶¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVxBluy2DVwjp8Cau7wnqcfHySKLbLLwy9lyAF/se1otkVWFguY/j@3u6R6JIkGgUCjwz3//7z///dc/f/36R2bENjLyr//n9@v3PxHv1xHnz/z1@WIbcb59/8xPrld8nfPn8@680v3B1zjfn@/eV4v7DrlufX79/bOP6wLvK18ffb98/93nzWvdcf3lPs7HmAOez/Ae0jWgpJF@f2t9577SPtYEnM99jjvhka47JkxUzKFEHCPpj@efvH9x3/Ke0TmEa7bmlNE6XB@eX5jTcT/SfIT7wu8nuAZ8zCkz158jntfIxFt@PrwWgywEHhpW6h42LMpcQJyD69NjXPZyXSJwbdZNxLym5cFk4Ozj3fmJ1294Ec7/GqPYB17qNWix0aqnpa0njDqh7@@uuVubCx4Qrnwtf8Jv2KC/f7uNfB7evSlCtnNcq5lsMXMGwS1MKwEfQNN53mHtrjVh39@/jWKa62dG5Cnnhrku@L7ifOT11LmGEveF/O4ImvPr1vvAS93P8IK1P2dh2rz1Tzv4ncAB1Q2Ka7KMdgfLu59iOVRwM6n@J6bnhE9yerw1i8e4xoFv0TGCe1gmsQ9eaTLapGcWFxw46uSx3GYMuzKDfXA6w9BRzvW4jIoDU@AY5wL7y6b6/Rqe3h8fg7dqYnAEc0dHkHMHbeQ50Exgj6lXZJsubot23j2o5XH5AdV9Bhv752s48s83joGLNIcCDnL54o8Fr8EqTiBHkDiBADnMYsdcnqDdk@AS1rxQsCEjpj30tlYdT1qvpov38Z9Js8MhPsS9wMS45cgrAJEnRnwSJQBEtcoALFYdc6KXIndk7Od2XOjzKMhGFgQGOxwfYG43HVd4/w7eL7PzbGBL4l//GGHCtpg2OoZpyIEIb2Noim6aAMc0uIewzUF@F2BcN0FZZQJViUgivLOljchPzAAL/dA1zCj@Ze1/2MHzQSmG4ljWSu4j2LHw1snMEtsBo8Lm1sF/f/I1xP@JuaOxFrQV6zsIdBjVg6cTdzK3ctYcpAB95/XA8hgy5KO3wMvIDqj4@SGTsMgPfcv5ZmUVZm0/j2mHGpzIfMGKNmG6@O4X25Z6jYXaI6Kd6NusovoIi/0Ddx5GcHroeQV2kYqys8E88wVMYI3pFLtWVrF2N@yYfUTjuzH5@Pi1NNsxMIVblon5BKYw3m2Ca8O1J9iPnIGJbseIJixKFi2QjtOTtD6NAxFFzuClkj24vqpzX6FiBOfTzfawcD8QqbRZHyW/NA08DgVBsI/DwKB0JgIBnh4d/GhNDa53DfxDdMkPzXRSjYOKDijwrUGyXeJuZYKAiJJ00NZs46/hIjHkXDREGM680zEMidbtAkwidE/tsh08l4ZgBXJfztzQ69QVQ4QTqYko4U/nSqLCw2UluN8ldb7/gCE8hBIdAeXcPoviFI3CIHA7YqJgTcQXEg/FQDBlGxSaitI8mUUF/ItII@JmZdRMCzLvQ9kbjE5pMknkLgQc1T7Iik5bO4bblcLPEuTU3VoYAF4VN9p90JJGCbRMBivc82Su9coEYuO3AE8qRfLxJIVNxh0NtFxAvFyABUM8IGjw6GGCn5lHWd6I0OQcqNs0NCTFE9jX6O8K@mRA4uhCxQ1o@wacmcRZnLfwb5gTVhp/XRiyOM6bGXPWdLuhqCksFpMjPgZZOGIc645ytnsCFZOwpQc4Uf@uMPjxUCtYRhLEd5OLjyghXfPM43HRJTiZIKJ5wUZBuuIUZxpJPpkmssIS5uJasgk@Ewx7jLaMBjsVOFuiUQoEfGC9kd9TIA0xz1AsCO5LZD1GmHTBhlnAJ6G@AeJzjS7AERu/DMaXUlHA@P0aNQ1S0jwFzGVXL2krIY23QdigU7kPKk9tI7v6ovggwUwZjoNs8BAtKFZHuSYaaF0l3kYyNUb772s4J8D@DBNPJRqSmDDHtVrD7ML/fIBFdcIupawtPScZ4kdLyqCAGdl3hpLO9/Pu1PDHBP/9Vfgm@WGIGLDfKYeIFMTO8Oye19cwtRliN73HLVE5oqSCnPAZAK4sZxB07LKPcMwxwXIhVDRbLDEspVBP/lHLTtWoBdZvLqcLxxvgZkSKXlkkKooiZROVmSkJooHUPgAqvpZJlAgVbo@LEVgHKhufEPNjhTgt/89FNq4yacX6VUAj4Qyq6/eLrRjPEZbbcLIFWxvHHcUlNt5DFdsZgDUvvY26DBBtDYlhsiWUe3ReboXYiggi@qkSZrrEjhItKq@@Hh6/RKoHNLV92FAiGbOqZ0LKlkLRaLayY2I0fe3@kGatJV3rXJFjyV11K4stY@ItF3YYBavS2ZTTq3ZoG11@F0o9STIuOoQuanLBHqsAlo7hGS9yMSmBZXr/XtJNTLArj7@yc7UJ41gjiqsI1rmwYbIEIpSsEw2DL/GytkTFQyrRqJo8hpVGalUJoqiVrG14MZRSr6K4EA0IOUEVbriCMDr9nkZMlzHUAlMV7SXvgWljx7B1CiqjS/7NfkEYs89UbH1dREUjiLAKyx0uec8MV1SlIF5rVCqVu@IyuihZfxHihPVlpcbLBFdXODDWYtSBVT@lmyWEs36UKCjHIoyqQpqXAPaITm91X2MfYYmfKtDC2WAGPEWxRuDOsWrJlSRXWZEahyjzJOsQagXKGk6DgCqUPgiWigoKQRp9DCdJ1QGyntQ/jfFZRk2ZlTtlBlC8tHCa3geVanohWalcBJS9ExWp8Iy3HfiUK028/neMTv6XqMt1xRly1jUZZ/zn8JgQR3RNmnwtIEFwItQUyrl/MRowG9LFDRFakoiQnLPorzARZdarViB4H6aOMDU4Ir32rErT8AyPH8pbpBN8MYXR2TSFn4VCiFncumTXbaDGn/t5oM6AbIj/VL@E/F1SXYa8AsXzHbU0jYaolETE9lOId6uJZ1AflrGoluKpx6Zvo3wQYfLE5hea0TK6pxBTC0phbA6DTzQ5X9XViYi3z9VLuroNC4xFlcA8l6WkStBFlPKgSqrNE8jIV@9lFUj5G8LzwhgaqbYpyz1z967@r4qm8LI3dCURHJQfFlp0K8KQz0nfRyclkH0RnqTu4mkgcqkqcasJ9NVTbjLya2MZU4En0apiVSeJNOk@sndFDTGKdrKZFoG21yWyeGFanz/Gk3upkDCazjD6ekQ0he5ULtAAzJ9pP26rSxRfxVO12/N/@4ishR3FrkiYhjSsQdCiFIo7VQr@3sZToTCjk@nypBbaF6EZwLZtRPqCIWEY7hmojJtP9V8jsixxpC8vPRd9ujmYt9hVEFZQZVhpuS1thdqAyD2SM@lOdMCaxgQtsSZaKdrGmugWaROXsDhkSbG0hQ/7aFXVPyRtTCbr1iz5vOo4SzdLhBFWheHKw7mfrF2T2jPr4H9aMsZQBhRwX6OtGADJYvy5rbUhIaASM442wqnaJN6mQ02TbdikVeuPUl2LXs4lO8yVyntKQGRkQRmWSdGChM8sI2zoGtMNgSRbLOBGL2svYUkryAkbUm8tkTZasGJNUFVB8FrMDql2Nj1YCtYxAOGGD6sVaepv2Wbm0Zdq1zVVExouP6ephdy6oZrZHoMjao0lbIWszs70ckNq62qkzMvSe6rIB3NKV2RaHEGctRzHLZOFKor6OJ2orU2bk8B@cuWg4gAuQd63P0YlYaJzSoqDjpGmCtOfdMBmweH5x57UfVQdRJWq9f19wcq1eCBlKd0RJVoYlS8LyLm7P7TMfk0aywRonSJt9OR8AdtZhdCuhYaswljPHbJMWan@Vh@YzVEWiPuaNhr@QOgbdALuiAiMqEUFxBz9syJLFapdBiGqTw4rVU6aImbNkuD73E38Ke5AN4dMxvBGCT/RTb740Ny3jVLG7g6UKNC5qMfbToXoEwfjyJyp113bEzWYD2H3RsvbsU0xivClT0duRVOsCQOPEe1T//HW9pFtwx01EJ7n1jJ5s/33ikydfgCqoB7B4ARGhGuWDMcgVwKu6D5sE0VpAQ/bacL4ixbZ3MzEeHEKjew3o2mLghBoMwMlm8lpm5bnesQO6aKO0ZXC9O4R2B/b8XVR0b3tD46m5Cam9LLNYYWpKMd3sMYWlUk2c5GTaTZ3AosI9ZqM35Rds@0O3YaLXkWq21wPhXOk8402pETXPPVAzYg@D28FllT1oZ1qTfqctDj12CLo6ESux1OxjViGTmJaig2eAJPaabb4qkpnsi1bM4nX6BTCU9ecBShyRhTJ9bOoFbga3nuZa@lOkfSwayJlXU97SJU2QM71eo1SNNIap2daS0mYhUHdCQBclGIRgQ5Se2GccjsK8glXNrF0kaSqdDt3jFhoWlAq3EB5PilFdAhHcX5C9Va6qkhOo4qwa39u2m6nx0pbSRG9Tfou2fihp9b7K/HbRR1W@j25mKLdT15TrL2levZR/pDwpeuiZQyviqrILp8rx5@hTdkwt3IQVw/DNG2rtQmpZ9jz2gzS8lbL3A8TLb6RC7Yk9RHQuX5cnu4L/dGJQvA0R57x0jJba7K7bUF6DWeHO/d6FipmyniLlrw5g@lJ0WkItWP4HFPZpCI8OoYWviXTpDJLiEEedOoDq3e2EaZ9nzj9Irbcu8P8uEO@NGemdRrphReSm@I5W9liU3cKVAoVSIgfdZost60n6ynm/qFnuju/xkg6arM5b3CvWUOlkUsSCBmZc1e7cy9pvIAHGh2C75ylkxK30bp26jQsBswMOFbcDndWzT6aNg1X8kQyex9hu2GCEeQxhH51agZzVZ0cLbXZEkz8bmuCSCk9x8en2jwoPPzJpmvTNYe5ls6cXk8vMAoOpVlTcE@xTGE4EXI0B1QYskT4S3vAmdUEEiue7uTZsjAzMPGBnCruilJDFtFPVXeGPcG44syoB24I1hGGPeMH2VFxZscIc@SgKpCLezFn2kqHSpP8P/UJaV9ZFyc7QXIrHOIzk6JLp4iUzHgiZt1Ru/3pTmnbatP2X4UVrRWKELMUrVEv7jLY@RJW@I32yjRSNQXUfNSix0N4D91M7IHnvZX9lSq2SFjSHFIM0ob5@22IdL2yASSfcAIJmJv3yzWh79fzzt//vj//9etv) Basic RLE compression; pilcrows mean this is Windows-1252 rather than ASCII.

Comment: I actually used a Retina program to create this program of course but sadly I failed to make a copy of that program.

Comment: It looks quite pretty in the TIO link with line-wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

## 23. C#, 14991 bytes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace crashTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            string e =
            "klbahihjnihihojklhlhijnihihjnbainikikjnihikjnobahihjnikiklhjklhohjnifahlhihjkbaihljninihojnohlhicahjklbahljnibahbaihjnieahihjnljnohcaihihijnbaihijnihlkijklnihjnikihbaijnihlhljnicahlhijnbaiklhinjklhojnlklhijnlnljkldahjnbaiklkojnbaihbaijnbainihbaijnohokohjklhlhijnohohokjnibahjklkjnihljnbaicahinjkdaihjnohokohjklkljklkjninihijnohjklcahjnihojklhjnlnihjklbahijklhihljnobahljkojnbaihijnidahikinjkohihjnikohjnobahihjniklhikjkokjnlnljkohljnohokohjnohokbaijnbainbaikjnikihbaijnicahljnoheaihijnlnjnifahlkijnihjnbaihljninihijnifahihlhjnikihihjklbahihjklnjnohlhihinjnlhijnihlkihjbahjnoheaihijnlnjnohcaihojnihihjnikihohjnbaicahikijkokihjnihlkljnbainiklhjnohlhcaihjklnljnohbaibahijnibahjninlnjnohodahjnohlkcaijnlhlhijnikikljnikinljnohohokjklhijnifahibahjkcaihijnikohjneaikjnihicahijklcahijninihojnicahihjnohikljnohohokjnoheaihijklhikjkcaijnbaihikinijnihikinjklkjnbaiklhikijkbaihijnbaikihihihijkldahjndaihonjndaihlhihijnbaicahinjnihihjncaikljnbaihijnifahihikjnohikjnieahihjklnjklnjkldahjnohlhohljnihikihjnikinjninlnjnbaicahinjnicahijnbaibahlhihjnbaikihihikjninikojninlnjnbainihbaijnihljnifahlhihjnbaidahlhjnikikljklhlkjklnikjnifahinijklbahljnohikljnlhijkokjkojnbaininljnikohjnohlhiklhjnihikikijklhihihjnbainihohjnobahljneaikjkbainjnifahikljkdaijnihikojnihbaikjnibahihjnbaihihjnikljnbainikihijnohbainljklhihjnihihijnbaicahinjklhbaijklhijklhinjnlhlkjnokihljnohcaikljnlkjnbaihieahjnohbainihjnbainiklhjklbahljnohcaihlhjkdaijnodahjnbaihihjkcaihijnbaihihjnbainihohjnohlkbaihjnikihlhijklnljnohlhihikijnbaidahlhjklkikjnbainiklhjnikihjnohjnoheaikjnihikikijnohocahijnikihikjkohihjnibahbaihjkldahjnikihlhijninlkjnbainikojnohlkcaijninijninihijnbaikihihihijnihijnlhokjnohgaijnikihbaijnlnjnifahihikjninbaikjkohijnbaibahlhihjkbaijkcaijniklhikjnokihihjklbahihjklnjnifahihlhjnicahihjnikinljklhihjnohlhihikijnlnihjklhihljnikijklnjklnjnbaihihjnifahihikjnidahikinjnikljnifahihojnohlhikojnihihihijnobahihjkcaihijninlnjkonijncaihjnifahikihjkdaijninijnlhlhijkdaihjnlhlkjnidahikinjnohfaihjnihikinjnikihjkohihjnifahihlhjnikohjkokijkokijklhojkbaikjnohcaikljnbainihihihjnieahihjnbaiklkojnohbainljklhlkjkohjnohohikihjnbainihohjnohbainljnlhokjnidahikinjkohjnohokohjklhohjnikihohjnikijnbaihikibahjklhinjkonijkbaikijnbainihohjklhbaijnohfaihjnlhjnbaikihihikjnokihljnoheaihijninikojnohokbaijkohojnohbainljnlhlhljnohgaijnohokbaijnbaiklhikijnihinijkonijkbaihijnocahijnikinjnohcaihikjnohlhohljklhljkbaikijnohlhiklhjncaikljnihlkijkbaihihjklhlhijkcaihijnohocahijnbaihljnibahlnjnifahikihjkohjnlklkjklbahjnokljninbaikjkohijnbaihihjnikbaijnohbaibahijnikikikjklnljnohlhdaijnohlkbaihjnodahjnbainikojnikihjnihlkihjnifahihojnlklkjnbaidahlhjklhlkjnohohikihjnbaidahlhjkbaihihjklhlhjnifahlhihjklhohjklkihijnbainihohjnbaihikinijnihlhljnlnjnohlhihinjnibahihjninikojnifahlhihjkojnohcaikihjklhikijnbaihieahjnihjnibahlnjnibahbaihjkbaihihjklklhjnihbaihijnifahihihijnijnbainikihijnifahikljnihlhljnikikikjnohlhihikijnihinijninlnjklnihjkbaikjkohijkbaihijnlhokjnlhlkjnihlhljnihbaikjnohcaihikjnohfaihjklhihljnihihihijklnijninbaikjkljnihldahihihjnbaininljnohlhdaijnifahinijnbaijnohbaicahjnbainihihihjkbaihljniklhikjnifahibahjnohikjnihiklhjnbainikihijnikihihjkohikjnbaiklklhjklkijkohjnlklhijkldahjniklhihijndaijnokljnohodahjncaikljnohfaihjnbaiklklhjnohohohijnbaininljklnikjnohohjnicahljnifahikljninohijklnihjnobahihjnokihihjklkihijnijniklhikjkohojnbaiklklhjklnljnohlhibahijkohojnihidahjnlhlhijnoheaihijnlkjnihikohjklkihjnlnljnibahihjnbaibahlhljnihiklhjnifahibahjnbaihidahijninlnjnibahbaihjninjniklhihjkbaikjnikihjnikiklhjnicahohjnlnljnicahljklnljnohlhohihjnljnikohjkokljnbaiklhinjnbaihikinijnihijncaihjklkijnbainihohjklhbaijnikihikjnohohcaijnicahlhijkbaijnohcaihojklbahijnohgaijkcaihijnljkdaijklhikijkokihjnifahihlhjnicahohjnbaibahlhljkohihijnohbaibahijklnjklnjnohcaikihjkldahjninbaikjklhohjnohocahijnbaihijnohlhcaihjnikbaijnohlhibahijnbaiklhikijnohlkbaihjninbaikjnohohokjnikihbaijnbaiklhinjkokijnibahihjkokihjnohokbaijklkikjnbainihohjnobahihjnifahihihijnbaiklhinjnobahljninjnihicahijninjnibahbaihjnbaiklhinjnbaidahojnihihihijniklkjnohohikljnbaidahojklnihjklbahljnohokohjklkihijklkljnihjniklhihijkokjnohlhikojnohlhdaijnohlhibahijnbainiklhjnbaijniklhihijnojnohohbaihjklhihijnihbaihijnohohokjninihojnbaidahojnikikikjnohokohjnljnohcaikljnlnljnojnodahjkdaihjnbainikikjnicahohjkonjninlkjnibahihjninihijnohohokjklhlkjkbaikjnodahjnicahljnbaikihihihijninohijnohohohijkdaijnlklkjklkljklnikjnbainihihljklhohjnbaininihjnifahibahjkohljnbaihikinijnikijklkihjnibahjnifahikljkeaijnbaihljnihbaihijnbainihihljnihikinjnohcaihojkokihjnihlkljnohohokjnikihlhijklkihijnohohcaijkohljbahjnbaiklhinjklnihjnohlhdaijnokihljnodahjnbaijnohohohijnlhijnohcaihihijnihlkijklhlhjninijnicahljkokihjkbaijnojnohfaihjniklhihijnihicahijnifahikihjnbaihikibahjnihihjnohcaihlhjkdaijninohijnohohjnohlhohihjninijneaikjncaikljklhihjklhihljnohlkcaijklhihijnikljnihlhljnbainikihijklhihihjnifahikljnbaiklhinjnohjkbaikjkbaijnohlhiklhjnihihjkbaihjkbaijklkihijklcahijnihbaikjnifahinijnihiklhjklkihjninjklhijkeaijnihikihjnibahihjklkijnohohbaihjnohlkbaihjklnijnbainihihljnikihohjnicahljklhihljniklkjniklkjnbaiklklhjkokijninihijnokihihjncaikljninbaikjkohojnihjninikojnbaikihihihijnbaibahlhihjnifahikihjnbaiklklhjklhbaijnifahinijkohihjklhohjnihlkijneaikjnohlhohljkcaijnlhokjklbahijkohijnbainihihihjkbaihihjnlnljnihojnbaidahojklnljnohcaikljnikinjninohijnifahikihjklnijnbaihihjnihlkljnikihihjnohohcaijninlnjnohodahjnihikjnohgaijnohikljniklhihjnikiklhjnoheaikjnohokbaijnikijnifahlnjnifahikihjnbaikihihihijnbainikojnohohbaihjniklhikjnohbaibahijnibahbaihjnobahihjnbainihihljnlklkjnohlhikojnohlhibahijkbaijnbaihihjnibahjkokijklnijnihlkljnbaiklklhjnlhjnifahikljnbainbaihijkljklnikjkohihijnbainikojklhohjnikjnihicahijnbaihikibahjnohbainljklkojnibahjnohcaihojnlhihjnocahijnohohjnihikohjklhinjkdaihjkohihjnihihihijnbaijnbaiklhikijkcaikjklhinjklcahijklnjklnjnikjnojnlkijkdaihjnbaiklhinjnbaihljnihojnikbaijnikihihjkbaikijnlkijklkihijnohohokjkonjninikojnlhjklkljklbahijnohlhcaihjnljnohikjkokljnbaicahinjnihljnbaiklhinjnikihbaijnikbaijkokihjnokihihjninjklcahjnieahihjnihljnifahihikjnbaibahlhihjnohlkbaihjnifahihlhjkbaikijnohlhdaijklhbaijnbaiklkojklnljklhojnohohohijnikihohjnihikjnicahijklkihijnikikljnifahlnjnihikikijnikinjklkihjbahjnohlhohljninihojnohohohijnojkohljnojnbaihidahijklhohjnohbaibahijnifahihlhjnohcaihikjnikikljklhijnicahijniklkjnifahlhihjnbaijnikihbaijnoheaikjnbaiklklhjnohohikljnihbaihijnohbainljnikihbaijnohlhibahijnokihljkdaihjnihlkihjnibahbaihjklnihjklbahihjklnjkbaikjnikihlhijbahjnbainikojnihikohjnokljklhinjnohcaihihijniklhihijklkikjnikihjkokihjnihlhljnihlkijnicahljnohgaijkbaihljnohbaibahijnbainihbaijklhljnihojnihikinjnikiklhjnicahijnohlhihikijnijnicahijnikikljkohljnbaikihihihijkokijnikinljndaijninihijnbaikihihihijnohikljnbaibahlhljninlnjnoheaikjnifahihojnifahihikjnokljncaihjnbaidahojnifahihikjnohlhihikijklnikjnikikljnohcaikljnijninbaikjnihikihjklhihijnlhokjnihldahihihjnikinljnihlkihjnikikikjnohbaicahjnohlhikojnikihikjkljnbaiklhinjnbaininljnohbaijnlkjnbainiklhjnifahinijnohlhohljnlnljkokljnihlkihjnohcaihikjnikijnbaicahikijnikihjkldahjklbahljnihikikijninbaikjnohjnohbainljnbaikihihikjnbaihijnohlhicahjnbaihidahijnohlhihikijnbaininljnihikinjnihikohjkeaijkeaijkdaihjklnjklnjnikjnlklhijnbaininihjnbaijklhihljnohocahijnbaiklhinjkdaihjnifahibahjklnihjnbaicahikijnohfaihjnbaihidahijkohojnikljkcaihijnifahlhihjnlkjnokljnohohikljniklhihijnbaidahlhjnihikohjnihikikijnlnihjnihinijnikokijnbainikihijnlhlkjnlkjninlkjnifahibahjkohihjnbainihohjnohlhibahijnifahikihjnlhijkbaikjkbaikijninlkjnihiklhjnljninbaikjnohcaihihijnibahjnlklkjklhbaijnlhokjklbahjklbahljnihihjnbaikihihihijklhlkjnifahibahjnbaihijninjkokihjnohlhicahjnohlkcaijkonijnljnihlkihjklnihjklcahjklhikjnbainihihihjnohlhcaihjnihicahijnbainikihijklkihjnobahihjnihlkijklkojnbaibahlhihjklkjnlkjnbaiklhinjklnijklhohjnifahlkijklhohjklhljnbaiklkojnbaiklkojnibahihjnbaiklhinjnihikihjklhlkjklhohjklkjkbaikijnlkjnihojnohcaihojnohlhihikijnokljklhlhijnohohbaihjninihijnbainihbaijninihojninlnjklhljnikihlhijnokihihjnohcaikljnicahijnikjnbaiklhikijnihikojnbaihijndaijnlnljkcaihijnohlhohljklhlhjnbaihikinijnihikinjnihiklhjklnihjnikinjklhikijnohlhohljnbaihikinijnihihihijndaijnlhjklhlhijklhohjnohbainihjnljklkljkokijnohlhihikijnohjklklhjkbaijnohocahijncaihjnohohohijklhinjklklhjnohcaihlhjnohlhihikijnbaikihihikjklnikjnifahikljklhlkjkokjnohocahijnlklhijnihiklhjklnihjklkjniklkjnohcaihikjkonjnifahihikjnifahihlhjninbaikjklcahjnbainikihijklkljnbaibahlhihjnikinjklbahihjklnjklbahihjklnjnohohikihjnohlhcaihjnohgaijnbaiklkojnibahlnjnbainikojnohcaihihijnibahlnjkohjnohcaikihjklnijnifahlkijnohbaijninikojnohohbaihjninihojklhikjnihjklbahijnbaiklhikijnihjnbainihihljkcaihjnlhijnohlhohljnohodahjkohojnlnljnihicahijnoheaihijklhihjnikihikjkbaihijninohijnohlhihinjnohfaihjnohcaikihjnikihihjnohfaihjnbaicahikijkbaikjnbaininihjklhihjnbaicahinjklhikjklhinjnbaiklklhjnoheaikjklnijnlhjnohohjnokljnbainikihijklhihljnohlhihinjneaikjkcaikjkljnifahlhihjnlklkjnokihihjnohlhohihjnihojkcaihjnihlhjnicahlhijklhljklhinjnobahljkbaihihjklhinjnidahjkljnbainihohjklkijnohikljkohojnbainiklhjnihjnbaihijkokjnikikljnbaiklkojncaihjnbaiklkojnihinijnohlhohljnohohjninikojnokljndaijnifahlhihjklhihihjnikljkojnlkjnihihihijnihlkljkonjnbainikikjnihojklkikjnobahljnlnihjninihijklkikjnoheaikjnifahikljnbaihieahjnbainihihljnohbaijklcahjnbainikikjniklkjnbaijnijnoheaihijnlhlkjnikljnihljnohlhikojnikljnbaidahlhjnicahlhijnbaiklhikijnbaihidahijnlkijnohokbaijnifahihikjnbaihikinijninlkjnohbaijnohohokjnifahinijnohokohjkohihjninlhijnikokijklbahijninohijklkljnifahihikjnlkijnlhlhijnihlhljkohlhjkohlhjklkjkcaijnbainihihihjnohfaihjnohikjnikihjklhojnidahikinjnicahlhijkbaihijnohjnbaiklhinjkbaikjkbaijklnijkohikjnbaihieahjnohcaihojnoheaihijklkojnihlkihjnifahibahjnihihihijnbainikihijnohohikljnlhihjnbaiklklhjkobahjnicahljnifahihihijnlnihjnohfaihjnibahjkohjnoheaikjnbaihikinijnohikjkbaihljklhihljnifahinijnibahlnjnikjnikihikjnoheaikjnihijnohcaihikjnlhokjkbaihijnohlhicahjnohlhihinjnohcaikljnifahihihijnohjkokihjnikljnibahjnlhlkjklnjklnjniklhikjnoheaihijnihihihijniklhihjnohlhcaihjnikiklhjkbaihijklhijnbaiklklhjnihikojklkikjkdaihjnihinijklkijnbaihidahijninohijnodahjnifahlnjnbaihljninihojnihinijnobahljkbaihljnifahlhihjnbaidahlhjkcaihjkokijnohokohjnikijnohocahijnihlkljnlklkjnohbaicahjnohcaihlhjnibahihjninlkjniklhihjnikihihjklhinjkohojnikijnidahjkbaihihjnihiklhjnihlhljklkikjnohohikihjkbainjnikljnijnbainihbaijklklhjnbaibahlhihjnbaicahikijnihikihjninihijnohikjnohokohjnlhijnohlhicahjkohihjnlhlhijnbaihihjnikihlhijnbaibahlhihjklhjnikjklhjklhlhijnicahlhijnifahinijnihldahihihjnifahikihjnbaihikibahjnobahljninihojnlnljniklhihijkohjklhojklbahljnohlkbaihjnbaininihjnljnbainikojnoheaikjnbaihidahijnikijnbaihihjnikjklhljncaihjkokljnikihlhijnbainikojnohcaihlhjnbaiklkojnobahljnbaicahikijnbainbaikjnihlkijnohikjklhbaijnihjklnikjnohohikljnifahlhihjnlhihjnihikojnbainihbaijklkjnibahihjnihlhljnbaihikinijklnijnidahjnikijnbaiklhinjnihldahihihjnidahikinjkdaihjnihlkihjnbaiklhikijnihojnlkjnbainihihljnlnihjkohljnidahjnikihbaijnohlkbaihjnibahjnikinjnihihijnifahikihjnihikinjklnihjninihijnocahijnlkijnbaibahlhihjnohgaijkbaikjnifahibahjnihldahihihjkohlhjnbaikihihihijklhikjnbaiklhikijnohokbaijnikihohjnlnljnoheaikjnihihihijkohojnihikojnihldahihihjnohokbaijnikjnlhlkjklhihijkohjnbaininihjnifahihlhjnbaininljkbaihljnbaiklhikijnbaiklkojnbaicahikijnidahikinjnikihbaijnohokbaijnbaihidahijnbaininljnbaiklhikijkobahjklhijnohocahijnlhlkjnlkijnbaiklkojnohikljnihikinjnbaibahlhihjkeaijnifahinijnohohjnohcaikljnbaihikibahjnihlkijkcaihijnikokijkohlhjnikihbaijnlhlhijnohohcaijnbainiklhjnihjklkjnbainikihijnohbaibahijnikbaijnicahlhijniklhihjklhihijnbainikihijnibahbaihjncaikljkokljnbainikojkohijnoheaihijnifahlhihjnlklkjnibahbaihjnohcaikljkbaijnbaibahlhihjnifahibahjnohbainljnicahohjnifahibahjnbaininljnohlhdaijnihojklhikjnlhokjnihbaikjnobahljnlhijneaikjnohlhihikijnihiklhjnokljnbaihidahijkohlhjnbainihbaijklkihijnohbainihjnbaikihihikjnbaicahinjklkjnikikljnohikjnifahihikjnohlhcaihjkbaihljnifahihlhjnihijklkihjklhihihjnohlhikojnobahihjninohijnifahihlhjnbaijnlnihjnohcaihikjnohfaihjnlnjkbaihljnohokohjncaikljnoheaikjkeaijnicahijnlhlkjnifahikihjnikihihjninlkjnifahikljklhikijnbaihikibahjklnikjnbaihidahijnohcaikljnohcaikljnlklkjnbaiklkojklhbaijnihlkijnbaikihihihijnbaidahlhjnohlhicahjncaikljnidahikinjkohihijkbainjnohlhibahijnihidahjklhlkjnbainiklhjnihlhjnohlhdaijnbainikikjkcaikjnlkijnohocahijnohohikljnihojkohikjnihikikijnojnohlhohljnbaihikinijnbaidahlhjkcaikjnohcaihikjnbaininljklnljnohohohijnbainihohjnifahibahjnicahlhijnihlhljnihlkihjnikihjnifahlkijnicahohjkokljnbainbaihijnibahbaihjnihikikijklhikijnijnbainihbaijklnljnihidahjnobahljnbaidahojnifahlhihjnlhijnohlhiklhjnohlhibahijnihjnohbaibahijncaihjklbahihjklnjkonijnihbaikjklnijklhinjnbaijnbaicahikijklhohjnbainiklhjnohlhdaijkbaihijnoheaihijnihihjklnikjnbaikihihihijkbaihihjnobahljkohojnbaihihjnbaiklhinjnihlkljninbaikjnieahihjnlhlhijnohbaijnohcaihikjklklhjncaihjniklhihijkeaijnihlkihjnicahihjkokljnihinijkdaijklbahjnohcaihihijnbaidahlhjklhjnibahbaihjklnihjnohlhihinjndaijnohcaihlhjninohijnlhihjnlkjndaijkokijnbainbaikjkbaihijkohihijnihjnidahjnihjkbaikijnikbaijnlklhijklhihljnocahijnohlhicahjninlnjnobahihjnohohbaihjklhinjnicahlhijninjninihijnbaihikinijklhihihjkcaikjnlhlhijnohokbaijnlnjninlhijnbaihidahijnbaibahlhljkbaikjniklhihijkldahjklhohjnohjklnjklnjnohcaihojnohokbaijnihikojnbaihihjklkijnbaicahikijklkijkohojnikihihjklcahijnifahinijncaihjkbaihijkbaihljninbaikjnikihbaijnohokbaijbahjklkihijnihiklhjklhljnikikikjnicahihjnobahljnbainbaihijnicahljkohjkohihijnibahlnjnokljkldahjnokljnicahihjnihihihijnbaihihjklhinjnifahihihijkcaihijklnijnihojnihijkldahjkcaihjklbahihjklnjnihihihijkcaihijnikikikjnikjnbaijnidahikinjnicahohjnbaibahlhihjnohlkbaihjnikbaijklhihijnifahikihjnbaidahlhjkbainjklcahjnbainikikjnifahlkijnihikjnljkojnbaihijnohbainljkokljnihbaihijnohlhdaijnbaihieahjnikinjncaihjkcaihijnikihlhijnlhokjklbahjnbaihidahijnbaiklhikijnlnljnikljnobahihjkcaikjkokihjnohbaicahjnlhlkjnlnljnohlkbaihjkcaihjndaihonjklhikijnihihojkonjnlklhijninlkjninlhijnikihbaijnihicahijnohohokjnikihjnbaidahojnlhlhljklnljnlklhijnihiklhjnohokbaijkdaijnikihjnohlhicahjnbainihbaijnohikjnlhijnihikinjklkijklhihijnbainihihljnbaiklhinjnihikojklhojnbainbaikjkbaikijnbaininihjninikojnohcaihikjnihjnlklkjnifahikljnidahjninihojnbainihbaijklnijkokihjninikojnifahlhihjninijnbainihihihjklbahijnohohjklklhjnohokbaijnikokijnljklkljnohgaijkonjnohbaijnlkijnikiklhjnoheaikjnlkjklnihjklhlhijnohlkcaijnikohjninohijnihiklhjndaihonjklbahihjklnikjnijnibahjnihijnohjnikljkohlhjnibahjninijnihljbahjnibahjnbaijkohlhjnbaijnbaijnijkljnihljnohjnlkmkjnlkikjinijkjh";

            var o = "";
            var v = new Dictionary<char, string>{{'a', "1*"},{'b', "14"},{'c', "15"},{'d', "16"},{'e', "17"},{'f', "18"},{'g', "19"},{'h', "1 "},{'i', "1\t"},{'j', "1¶"},{'k', "2 "},{'l', "2\t"},{'m', "2¶"},{'n', "3 "},{'o', "3\t"}};

            foreach (var c in e)
            {
                var a = int.Parse(v[c][0].ToString());
                o += string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(v[c][1], a));
            }
            Console.Write(o);
}
}}
```

[TiO](https://tio.run/##dVvbjty4EX2fr2j4xePEMbK5B47zsgnykgCLrIE8OH5gqzVDDjnkpnvWycLwb@0H5Mccsa6n1M4C65HUkkgW63LqVGm5/Oxx9PH58/eX0u8P3/5weVofX9/g2auvR2vr8lRGv7z6y9rXc1l2d7xd//O0u/TX0v/1@uamp8f18l1a1sNyTpf8dr083Xy8OWz/LS1dLodvzuP@nB7pCl@f/12e0lNZDh9GOR3@lkq//fbpvL373ftDOt9fXth9/gQ/NW86rIc34fKz2o4pl/zQy/bveKgtt1z47KEft9eXWiqdb/8OvXe71vK8ecyzuzQf2s63@3PbLvT5qj7m1SXN@7bn5vXtz7xlO1r5RW3etaQ5WqHheOxWy/ZQl6HmM3SV3rEknuF2cRu/dJrF9qZKV9v2ytpOKcsNdfBr6RW0HD4cedSRbbnb6XaBZ7hdpAU3emAbbo5xomnbU7XJXb3w49vpXGkXGc6JFFn4XEqm1w0Sg05prmmb6LbA7f1D5Drl6VJuU@p1TozWNeglPAf6a6uaa0VZLYlvXXmc1mWXKgmSx282/fnTFC@/weY9/3bZximE3mx38sMUVByAN3Ko7sxXjWwynDs6KivaFJ/oVss8wHx0Dkez3n4iufF2bLPk148Tj9nqMhepmjp1kf7ww7SRrAy0LtrRReRNkluTaPTCm7PwWKy0dJGGodeqYuhKZUuWpOq6DcvmQts4dUIUcy5YtnleIRWnF9Aqpj6Nzn@baT8rmwhwSUXk5HtERkj/igXNHeL/VTiZtIQmxLvQVYIwAC@Z5dzU1HmOrNVTSe2p7iYI1j5/OSVVG7KIbWvIbqvMtxezfZHn3Jep0GIEnTZN1H6@lhSCJl/FbswPZbWNJls4xSuKTcOfkuwE6aCYhNgSSZFtytwaW@48aTwUSx63Yrs8V07qxN6m0yL7VGV1XrSuKmOsvA08Y9Byl8NCWy7THeqqaDOX5H4wLnsbVDxnJYUxWyER1QK7sSlhqWhfrAlD7bW6gKd6i/bXwr6GxaCOWtRKB53bZa8eYItsBP1K2/lKExO6TwWclDol1TnasDmBoJjk42QQNj6S/d5JgQtbLEb5voKcxDGzR2YtYxNyHfFJqX9mveEfNLJVcXWsRzIXdTRzdXVMqSzJ3jn3QbS0mwOT0MJq5QOOfJdKNs/Cm6jbA/56hp4hzpVDYWXNN9VkLZKlrWYOHBtB/xtJn10eqwzqH98mW4lxC2PpAL@vSjlv5KhKBjVlQjMs8H4xM1t02zkks7ZVxSvqxyFwG32EOTa@@14jvcZJ8ctTHHMaOhfaQLMDC2UsRXaoUz42b/dUImJBLGrGsrGiC2ZjGnSnandUiSmuVsl3clild@4MQpRa5OQhshJAc3fAbsX8hTkY8ekWgl2RhoyOLoSdHGqC/IJrROjXeB@ruoBu0d9jJG1LhBTqn3V69r6hGizWatq0MswCOZqzsrlJFImhkw6D89fIYdiSZYnegjVF7Jldh2@L6g4bhViwvCqDFYom3SX0PIYH@P38Vp7LKWHcCxurYbW7Hiy2wfyUoXBxl4aCFDmI7qIgxKPyDewcJJKYdjp2KVUQC6uawCT6SexB7djexDjKVIMcTi@iYoZXfT/6yJYBKBw2t191Kw0g5xFmbZGR0fcQUEozNMCvyFUkotrLUBtxA0Wi5nJzedL2n5I5fExwuspJ/bHhsapRathgtHyf99DcSN17g3RnBzslwNBWXTtUCesk5sUyA1Fdh@ySp4jLVMclkErB7Ki72CNLcBFReAruyWIr2DLrkCq8hBdwkQUyAnd4upvoxgEVdTU3yeOqp3waeGqxbZW1WPwAxJRDBuaew@UvEFSAuiYPuPlhr7blIlAo1T1r8xuq54sN80x2EewX3PLqqABC0OuDlLqZOZgsR00Fd4rRTOwiPU6FfPLmFzn1DMCXziTOCJYB2oB1pI6u2BEcPgwp8EM2kTWEfUJEk@QXzJkwlpLIWc2nqC9sql7scwraLufSaEq1qAOQrFPTijVB7M6e0skYhtDMmEKaixrJPrTawhfGLu3hmHIgNLpiVvGwjH40koM3FV9mDIpSJ2yg3agAnpPYEoBLVwFVZAUlCN0kId2lLrAZ6LZoVE4zWEWqAgTBcJwy2MgQfz0iWeZnIQHsz2KwuwZNGyX6PZhZY4KvKaGGUHHouutd0rxV00jVBXOvZjnueTh8ozYo/BWfrldJ950foIHZJYkh1JD1O/obYvoMkII5YP4eNk4DoQQBTcWHIzXRFNkoQ7lCrIxq1NVAbQeQJZEL/YQGMF2CUA8j6JUJLIORCP6AMBUoH41hgufl7Q2pSEttDe4zfLvbYe0rAVomoYFbk8zIQsm2OyrQ/W7iz8EXS@g7JlwoO51qgM9IMAFIbafsEgrNq2ls1SlbtgXGiybriR3harkmDJ0kxUtyAzYM5HSnZpsgrcBuLRLByXKWEO5JglM4BWIC4BdVnVIdpmTLr1qNfpL4om420IyBVdSiaEF4JodMRqgFD@I8qaSPFfBl1@V4tmy8V1F8bGYHEESBEWaJgp9cclXMhElr8@PmNbJGTZeAEpyqysrdKOPoZKxyf0q/y8uHMseIWA15uZobsvOkxYi9YqShuDJkAUGiaoYR@YuTN5ghiTo8ZcCFg50ojeWpzkf1HfMD6HrO8hiz3SzUoiyix2CpaIrhn@TiGryz5fVOpxM6Fv0FyTlFWpurthM3hvhLzC1BpiTmsQc8EiGY2lbi6IpjcyhpqYq4z9UDXh6BQ54PLMlT@/irzVHJ3Cppnbp2R9wlW4ruqTDmsDJ720rDkpq6OpkmHOQ@29EUmFnDSG1qLDfl50JJhRGDNmM9okNCYiUqsy7LKEBhkZOCVMVScM0GIy0rJLfqgzjaCTP4n1MCIp/kLcUsx61KQktysKRYATulCG6bPqQrhYRc7Z@RRW3OWZpJt@ppPUbbEjh/sS2TmNTrBFux6gLHwPQIF81ajVD8iuzO6JM4K5eQWs2/Fsvdm2TLPXAuXkCSDEEUyNANbnreV2lymKNVYbrnjrrvhmiJ7nXFU1@1CPlZIxULOS7Eb8O/FfGGwnpBgMaNq0RD6hDKsrUYNWcxsA44AKJDo6NZdKvO60FwftD4ImgCtF0crdVUNTsv0U1asY1pNcXNDYGwOxv1kXsKFwqpnAj2BqSr87b5S6U6R//d6mTAK@Sr/FC9LQ/lLC/E0c4YhMHJqNERDCUmNW0RK160sswprWxjbZhw7RyK@iAstXn9jbkBebt4krBYyEXMNzK@8sKHszxK1DjNCKREyEBYhBCaYxVZuWRXfEH0QRet5GgMsFtys4KDkUm9QGV7mHLtML2W5TlgGXAM6hR4A4GTqEmajbDjlOzHgrpXh7MHMnMaA4IC1HZsHZAAmZ/WovkxmeewylWsUBoKD6iLS6SNC02WptfrNLvh1PipxchoiAmtonFauj8lq35McY4YhoMubnzw2gEZIMfdwFpWgzNG6mqkNydchyMSU50lhbJW2aECyXFEMaqhKShfeH2YcoyKnF1mi@6xI2YochRGsHV3dvoLQjCr5q8p5pBDsCOaGNIFDz0w1lnsVxITwE8tBOhdp4xVUE7iGbA4FrIb83mMBLJzTjVALiYplfaRbgzOcSV8C49fQ/5EI1ufkRDHLeu/DforIFqqyThUpxQKSrRAbUtTDgRGZ4w4Rg5f7BpyY7dlViSolBkXVmK0dpzUcmRgxjHtyhsCkzsuSmFQSJ90E4a5EqCTjMLSGlhFrt@K/Ah@GfdcoVb0ShpwfZ7DM6LaDE5Jm4fi1ebD5hKp7j3Skb6xo3lL9Fkc0tlyLAHkHpKd7qpHPSlR23roaQIP4J7ny70r7Ls0WjO/vWuNYKpGiR5PWzQ4O6UthpkLtlJx9UF4dHV7ToCpe2N3qTy7YDDpcJGcC/NM5faxgcfyGiUvu@WHQN6H/RfrbeYpMjaZRLDJdFN17OMuBjhVyPy@yCVb@aR4HLWyhli110GUXfFUqAV8AOZy0lQa1yHoUje5xbUhymihLeKYoP@vxi67bGHKKdaMBc2yC52202O3h6A7xoCL3Qu00fabCNBBxtaJERmTAG0GpM3CWvaiNRAbwqgYJbSOyRvIconpmDW8dVS0xSNLJMmUOKnRk9o62PXvU7Ad5Edq14un4O5UiQa0gbmo4HHzYaZ2@xpRblB@V/cRA6klUmZ20C0EbabOA58SVsCRSh3aIYPQXRLmEtp1JO7zOGiea2gP0KoMNhFaMafVgi2RXORvqAWQwnkoVhxWnYPZlXuNzzW/AMWfXe@FkepSJQJoOqTs4CFlB0OBkZcVmpRjQSRQ4VaxDmn9vsHCMwXlsoRVEJCXQ9XE20QYdpuwlWQxPcpQkooNgkgpKahH0s0TMh11Sdjn4bmaMQeGZ70wYUFqRLJXevEiU2aNWB34To4f1uLBqcKanMYE0iRkNUD4CBF71RvWd27cNBc6LL14NsDxtlquqzoCgR3mKLQJDddFAywyTlnykrxjGu2FJzcIy5UMTXtJRQx1KNT0nssvEwwBkYTOIWiZaftOmp0@u@EBgW0toN4CrmX5WGzC/hVowa3lCn1I9nuCgB54ZAt8WJ8NUg5uQ1pYgDoY3Su2SmqJxwvZMRT4K26QA11ApaBnHmYUK2hzfh6hAddjLpRl/fsF9ZPQTlOqwrMlFNm1sCw7smgnSjOYy9UiKNVFda7tuhQC@P3kU2hu6M7onpIWFAzLKBAfmucaHPAylrj0Zj3Q5AygmLFAj762amGLSUe17MgGGtTJ1v5cMfZU7xPujk9PoXe9eQWoQYO90XK7FqQ8EAgAhwgtVKZb1WlyuQOaJKy3V4Vo@cfuYwwdTj4tKYGPw7ZD@/TADMrsUpo4sm@VJH5MuJ68a3RJV0Vb5FwstZP4r9XoodHjlCwnCv3V8TGfszEUIQ8f@f@WSesRuz8wRfAO0/4FMsQ/XyElwc9orNY9dnVGd9baN0oz5OX5SljhoDCwUzR1gpqshHbv6hUBTQ0FuXXMYIQjk@8@gMWmCNGdqdUSSS7h46fikWVYN6H53CbpY297yteb3E4KnXdFK/8kiq0vfM5SInbL@0p61l6EnVepoXwV6VwmYRXKWc@n9AWWvMuSuvce7pqEe@m75hTrCDC2HWE/OT/h5zUpGR1Ki@W6n0S@aMFPxfSbB@YKBE@JtG1/zXZouZZNKTGl9V7PsyR75gq2oVOAkEYFAvM35/fI8KM@kC99yM9e34RP/D6k82Ec3hyebT/sr3/Yrvf134c/FfqEMZ1/@MOS0/mlfC74x48fn6fnLw/PvvrJs08vPz4/0vGv6Hih41/T8YmOf0PHKx3/lo7v6Ph3dHxPx7@n40zHBzoudPzPJzp5oJP//kgndZ78gu9qdCx3PdKJ3NXnyS/5rkHH865POyHcjfOalny4nateDqUf1hfhhvi1pMonbfIp/enVN@l8WW8/vFvev/v5@1dvB39yefvixeurx8bhp29EfK@@Hpuvebr9c//@cT2nY1tf/X39bt2u0Ju@ev/ykPav@BTOthdcxvbYP87lab0d272fbj59@vz5fw)

Comment: Damn, even thought I juuuuust beat you, I guess that since the chain carried on from you I need to delete?

Comment: Arf ! I didn't see your answer until the upvote, you did a very well job. Maybe we should ask OP what (s)he thinks about it. @DomHastings

Answer (score 1):

## 26. Mathics, 52954 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[{8992,182,9484,102,119,124,9619,269,8801,72,8730,333,107,967,8470,951,316,353,190,8218,326,9619,100,94,44,969,98,125,97,949,9618,182,113,88,83,959,8734,230,87,38,167,76,59,926,68,963,8318,922,87,178,56,936,316,8218,9474,123,9,105,36,8541,81,965,311,65,947,8730,8729,178,8219,53,8313,299,8541,87,921,189,424,53,90,46,104,8532,8776,188,948,8721,8317,58,936,9668,9553,945,56,248,86,966,257,8218,8541,46,333,922,109,8992,188,103,8252,8318,9632,963,68,40,97,86,188,8993,9484,960,8992,8594,67,198,353,49,954,42,9633,9472,8253,8729,71,77,72,99,107,9552,951,63,424,936,8252,119,9650,9580,924,90,178,8252,122,60,951,119,64,95,353,73,8595,291,927,8595,8219,950,50,946,8308,108,8317,47,109,89,110,955,9492,953,9675,73,115,9559,8734,88,91,176,9556,89,166,88,8312,97,9472,8804,923,8542,103,177,956,8531,935,9565,39,120,119,968,423,8317,9572,185,1472,8311,107,99,125,78,920,79,8993,9562,951,257,8593,8805,38,8218,97,9488,8710,79,51,311,124,9488,37,57,71,48,269,98,104,41,914,934,122,98,91,9484,100,919,8313,97,947,70,932,916,54,56,68,951,8596,198,122,110,60,9618,82,959,8776,188,919,424,964,915,84,9474,43,185,8304,8801,8310,8312,8540,42,955,933,968,8470,924,8594,8531,299,55,960,424,119,171,63,353,275,950,8596,965,316,125,63,56,93,8800,9572,353,9650,931,122,93,959,8260,363,8219,8312,172,957,106,9474,326,928,53,58,8253,8242,353,182,94,424,924,949,952,77,87,124,55,965,8308,188,291,38,35,9632,9668,188,8596,230,8800,423,46,1472,363,106,925,100,937,967,46,60,969,8312,62,167,9668,70,63,927,958,919,72,179,161,166,8309,8597,8721,92,67,46,923,8721,32,957,8597,105,945,9565,8494,257,36,120,925,66,41,8993,100,9472,9633,117,188,107,8800,8596,964,92,114,73,87,115,100,111,382,9,8541,269,115,48,8309,269,113,230,187,113,958,947,966,123,915,963,8310,937,78,56,103,9619,178,105,9619,958,959,960,178,59,171,964,190,960,963,326,8805,919,105,98,126,108,8540,164,8800,9618,8776,70,99,69,72,9472,9573,90,113,9632,8313,33,9565,189,36,94,927,8317,965,96,8540,82,172,935,73,9492,9675,32,934,95,114,9553,55,120,40,9650,8543,929,950,269,8595,76,353,927,955,9492,70,8252,925,99,8800,9553,96,969,74,8595,915,52,83,101,923,62,97,88,80,926,9660,41,8253,937,86,918,72,44,8800,8710,9565,8729,111,8309,176,9556,932,8219,961,39,929,167,178,58,957,9618,423,8308,9572,8539,66,66,343,8304,275,102,112,9632,54,8304,61,44,39,9660,363,8776,8540,8219,106,8801,967,918,8309,107,9619,8252,914,39,9552,89,42,166,9580,167,922,9573,54,9617,918,953,8253,953,932,950,275,59,8710,8540,9553,108,64,8592,951,119,8541,9488,41,929,935,167,49,949,166,185,955,171,8710,9658,41,102,79,291,8539,8304,67,9617,123,167,382,964,921,83,74,120,65,78,969,82,103,326,9572,47,8992,48,9472,9618,118,43,8532,914,8721,968,108,9565,120,32,112,8597,935,8592,8311,959,8595,114,8540,80,9619,84,118,188,8543,190,8311,111,967,8218,8804,424,257,931,8992,969,120,8992,8993,90,968,8592,8317,9580,275,36,9496,932,39,90,353,123,64,104,39,46,94,9562,9572,45,8240,8597,925,9660,269,41,32,167,917,47,9608,269,38,964,113,945,950,953,117,50,299,124,1472,83,9562,37,8531,63,9658,8218,914,8539,8240,9562,269,177,956,8542,9532,9573,9660,177,948,8804,8470,73,928,56,9619,177,937,55,179,929,84,9553,97,116,8218,122,967,64,8540,74,8541,46,61,961,38,95,291,8539,929,311,969,230,424,112,968,115,248,8240,75,187,965,89,42,82,40,9562,8218,424,82,97,8721,122,8317,326,107,166,83,8540,9658,115,9,171,937,112,52,953,70,82,198,59,44,53,311,57,63,119,311,9,9660,114,8801,60,92,8721,77,311,52,230,9580,8593,257,248,925,952,299,89,8993,299,9556,9580,8531,9552,915,39,952,123,161,52,925,88,66,9565,8311,42,189,167,35,311,118,917,95,931,952,8532,124,46,9608,925,105,954,950,966,8805,8730,8801,424,71,424,9608,8494,117,8730,73,51,275,257,945,54,118,8992,926,8317,58,8218,166,932,926,119,49,947,230,936,8242,179,8992,924,927,8494,189,937,935,89,190,67,954,8730,8311,928,961,85,333,8710,8240,32,8597,8993,957,8993,8318,9650,9608,8597,9496,47,9658,71,917,189,101,8594,964,8597,8531,8240,111,185,8594,83,61,53,257,8531,80,922,914,949,106,125,969,961,59,363,953,71,114,8311,182,269,9552,299,958,929,77,8710,9556,9496,960,53,188,8309,919,311,8540,326,8594,108,9484,104,946,923,38,114,94,934,423,8539,106,8597,60,90,66,316,167,925,96,914,960,382,9668,923,9474,9474,49,44,45,925,68,59,8801,9532,9650,52,8253,63,176,74,113,102,275,959,124,966,8242,8597,8543,8776,110,8532,969,8494,54,914,54,56,8253,90,929,187,64,101,961,299,963,105,54,94,69,925,8219,952,363,8470,247,52,107,176,969,67,247,257,188,8805,9668,9618,8242,9572,958,85,95,952,333,178,179,189,918,8310,50,188,1472,924,171,67,9496,8304,56,931,9532,961,934,8747,172,112,299,103,8776,8252,917,187,65,121,343,84,964,8310,115,74,102,423,85,65,9617,9553,123,960,920,8595,85,124,952,8318,935,8310,8593,311,74,915,937,92,85,9484,920,269,8253,42,63,9492,949,9658,9484,8494,33,124,189,927,269,248,101,918,124,107,8309,9562,53,925,934,921,8253,8992,945,90,38,110,965,82,951,960,124,9632,915,117,33,107,58,82,36,257,933,9633,112,9650,932,9553,935,343,9633,9559,52,299,363,247,89,198,122,8311,967,87,9658,9619,103,59,353,77,9559,9488,929,84,102,112,60,92,9556,171,107,9617,43,925,114,9632,90,423,927,965,9660,60,247,102,113,9484,9675,247,9496,960,120,88,931,933,937,8729,187,38,179,55,62,248,8218,114,963,8596,9572,60,44,247,933,424,8470,178,423,9484,8710,122,8240,9572,95,9532,333,47,178,8219,185,257,47,8596,917,8260,67,53,8592,166,8311,44,918,960,74,8304,8240,8800,333,188,969,914,9573,111,75,93,9633,118,177,958,952,85,8992,50,9617,69,963,98,35,8721,75,46,9559,110,914,8470,57,9650,933,960,917,92,46,123,105,93,919,9660,8804,126,76,9,927,107,956,247,8542,963,936,187,9580,82,37,8309,82,74,8312,8539,949,8992,956,95,101,8531,93,923,8310,8543,9650,920,9496,8543,920,961,9633,8531,965,92,8539,110,111,8312,75,925,9488,230,8312,967,917,8541,8541,8312,105,951,8592,8539,8540,343,918,42,936,107,9617,77,93,8308,102,57,9668,111,931,269,967,8539,8801,958,257,76,40,121,956,56,927,8729,98,105,961,925,39,957,171,963,68,61,108,107,958,55,955,9559,123,110,32,9573,33,9668,61,71,8804,316,109,9580,921,311,122,9660,83,257,967,967,105,9559,42,8595,33,108,188,343,424,87,58,123,1472,122,117,247,247,932,72,275,113,97,86,121,247,8531,84,82,50,9492,922,75,9565,103,9632,9488,81,126,8542,87,110,89,8542,8596,55,178,58,954,8993,33,75,118,9496,122,106,931,957,9488,40,8219,9488,35,77,113,363,78,8593,189,926,937,94,182,933,185,76,54,8308,8310,8801,9573,917,58,8318,58,9580,9559,102,953,9562,83,946,164,49,269,179,121,968,198,311,108,966,9668,105,51,43,8597,9474,9472,64,9472,51,8801,86,8747,50,9532,98,9496,9650,185,182,177,67,8312,81,113,9484,950,937,37,333,9562,56,76,8242,51,8710,257,89,946,171,966,75,121,936,98,9556,917,108,43,382,166,97,9565,8729,8304,87,8710,94,65,73,44,8494,56,8310,71,105,8470,80,9496,945,82,9532,8594,161,91,119,84,917,9633,79,39,968,72,8594,8801,333,97,189,118,968,84,9660,124,40,74,269,113,161,9484,248,8311,101,8532,8313,43,9559,44,77,9553,109,333,74,8470,9492,93,929,248,36,382,9565,8710,167,59,172,106,8800,934,921,8592,41,8494,928,918,49,44,8318,9484,961,126,66,114,935,85,916,925,70,9660,164,124,182,70,8710,8304,122,8595,8531,46,190,931,117,968,46,934,8541,8253,8734,9492,929,114,119,925,9562,965,8494,8734,937,56,8310,79,8801,951,8532,291,9552,316,1472,87,114,947,51,190,8539,99,8596,100,8218,95,37,9572,9580,93,53,44,8318,8304,123,953,161,52,39,123,161,948,8218,961,8540,96,9618,92,927,8317,110,8992,111,957,66,171,921,935,353,8539,8730,185,8539,275,8252,8730,53,9484,87,9608,123,8531,9573,102,9565,949,70,72,39,112,230,114,80,299,8539,343,423,9580,90,948,1472,125,53,54,61,934,8240,952,51,937,9472,41,248,269,90,9472,958,8470,35,185,90,8801,275,58,8242,257,54,82,948,9,32,8721,121,63,8309,72,423,188,8317,924,916,257,934,8592,957,9608,257,8311,8540,70,9492,8730,161,103,59,918,60,61,104,953,956,114,966,102,291,9553,178,951,8540,8532,9675,920,116,8804,109,178,96,257,316,423,70,916,8309,8592,58,933,932,316,179,927,79,8734,51,55,101,299,945,54,9553,8531,8311,8494,316,919,965,124,8596,106,48,59,8531,100,8592,116,8592,965,967,424,107,291,248,9472,9650,40,106,950,8541,198,921,955,116,9633,90,922,8311,8308,161,8721,8539,79,8801,75,9556,248,9619,188,935,8218,59,8596,922,9552,8309,929,954,172,185,84,82,41,116,95,41,8993,43,914,8218,959,52,35,58,53,47,72,923,311,123,9617,965,59,166,8776,9552,9580,38,954,299,107,382,965,968,248,111,90,116,177,965,316,269,965,918,299,71,43,936,60,78,8805,956,8541,9484,950,35,968,8219,85,1472,71,9668,114,73,8710,97,33,8311,275,75,8730,953,87,36,920,924,8304,960,115,326,9496,36,98,9565,353,8805,8313,8313,316,95,54,8311,56,927,9658,9488,311,9556,8596,965,8734,55,957,97,171,69,108,8801,927,106,922,118,8218,8532,106,8800,178,382,8734,9633,96,917,87,382,924,918,920,963,118,8804,8252,66,50,116,8805,64,343,9572,257,8218,74,9474,176,87,112,9565,87,275,8597,161,8470,95,8592,59,917,8721,9552,9650,257,8470,66,424,70,179,343,936,9556,115,42,8805,61,71,423,8312,923,922,171,9608,957,257,961,116,9472,947,9618,46,9632,58,8540,8595,291,43,9488,928,248,8596,8594,119,114,964,950,929,85,55,382,89,382,44,117,921,8800,937,73,917,47,8729,269,9608,61,85,8594,8804,95,8710,48,35,109,178,40,919,114,961,125,9488,90,92,8318,8317,198,954,8730,58,8993,178,63,8710,8800,101,922,77,32,248,66,62,8540,927,41,82,52,9617,920,185,161,69,112,95,72,916,41,9562,311,41,363,936,68,46,8317,8710,93,343,115,8252,8800,8309,71,117,8312,8992,123,934,9633,936,100,9,921,113,113,84,927,46,9474,123,171,54,75,109,8543,115,99,9617,95,424,8218,50,76,8242,188,257,198,8470,8543,8532,9660,9632,9608,8734,164,117,59,47,164,963,40,9668,171,8252,8304,9553,423,8253,44,956,63,112,161,9492,947,9660,55,69,8318,958,424,914,956,8595,166,8311,8596,57,187,92,57,945,343,8240,956,118,326,931,956,59,57,105,8219,177,8597,95,8597,81,120,959,8993,100,84,9552,311,176,118,8311,964,9565,50,51,93,950,65,9573,124,76,164,118,61,44,161,8532,964,8805,8242,65,32,9565,958,8801,41,8309,36,8800,92,1472,919,66,8730,924,83,8532,921,969,80,114,9559,9668,8729,70,8594,9562,291,269,72,9618,951,935,9658,916,75,76,9,112,54,100,42,91,8310,177,8260,182,124,8309,108,91,43,9484,915,41,937,69,423,167,316,959,42,965,122,947,58,44,9562,54,959,64,179,58,118,164,99,967,969,90,54,50,8596,8542,953,103,9559,9552,964,52,8993,92,326,179,333,102,9484,933,102,81,93,172,113,52,83,947,33,8594,120,104,35,96,8470,105,9496,8993,9675,117,104,188,88,120,66,8710,8804,86,8542,8543,8253,9633,8242,9572,40,952,8710,8710,922,946,187,171,9632,8310,60,178,1472,161,53,935,948,98,963,123,922,9562,9496,95,91,1472,117,58,8540,66,107,118,8543,946,8734,106,9492,81,32,363,97,61,53,97,92,959,72,9565,101,121,66,923,932,950,8800,925,78,950,178,947,167,9552,42,8252,60,423,928,311,8531,33,8470,8253,113,61,109,9532,89,124,363,958,72,108,164,957,61,40,8543,86,167,921,43,9668,73,80,118,36,9552,63,104,104,109,9650,92,8260,56,9650,39,8992,8593,48,8801,66,958,188,8311,190,960,101,958,119,952,9492,98,63,8805,167,104,114,919,311,86,291,120,8993,8595,8540,9474,922,960,8242,63,920,86,101,8253,94,8219,111,291,8310,109,917,275,920,958,353,67,247,8596,69,929,39,961,9617,9559,915,37,925,8801,965,945,928,121,954,8593,66,8310,923,107,88,918,123,9650,953,112,8312,946,38,9484,79,68,111,74,32,9573,182,316,198,333,126,198,8992,122,85,915,100,91,116,101,363,96,9,937,79,60,915,952,936,8805,966,925,101,333,8730,8304,69,8312,47,104,299,8219,91,9488,917,915,125,8710,114,48,32,918,8593,1472,97,8494,126,56,37,9608,92,363,9580,8311,8531,171,8218,86,963,8804,8309,920,936,8992,187,44,9573,311,167,248,58,8470,177,9488,8594,35,8218,353,32,122,176,105,9608,38,299,947,9573,78,178,87,124,291,179,123,85,9675,8776,8805,8801,83,921,948,45,72,9668,333,88,8729,275,9496,95,926,178,36,8993,8218,963,8597,8730,110,121,9675,8593,8219,935,182,187,923,119,936,112,9532,8308,957,65,424,40,914,104,164,956,101,32,9565,353,8252,167,51,966,72,9668,117,65,8800,35,76,9492,914,257,166,89,343,110,62,79,8318,914,949,8593,8242,247,161,8539,115,926,91,951,36,86,83,190,32,8596,8253,90,114,947,275,932,946,90,924,8539,922,9618,958,8313,79,176,946,62,948,8596,959,120,56,9632,924,164,179,9572,953,39,103,9617,120,107,109,945,108,961,8317,9532,918,8710,1472,8595,33,119,947,189,9572,9474,190,93,8747,353,187,78,111,38,9632,78,112,38,122,326,47,8800,109,9650,75,70,9573,41,161,115,946,9472,89,85,39,955,103,45,122,8313,9556,124,8710,9496,382,929,915,123,248,311,83,933,98,73,950,84,316,382,66,45,51,934,8594,8539,96,968,54,58,9619,8543,39,77,35,55,423,44,106,9675,80,8729,32,64,299,8470,36,915,164,8734,69,64,178,62,187,8597,188,164,8310,49,172,109,966,248,969,963,102,951,316,423,8252,9573,929,72,8242,114,959,299,115,947,80,8596,8242,94,63,108,53,9572,8311,45,78,190,957,8540,925,916,957,70,8805,9660,9658,382,187,33,62,269,187,8311,949,48,84,9580,90,97,74,8710,343,316,8993,9608,104,120,1472,9675,86,917,9562,176,915,965,8252,8993,80,95,9650,32,9552,70,198,105,969,917,190,291,269,47,8539,326,9492,291,931,926,8470,187,45,9660,936,9619,946,934,164,8721,8539,9660,923,948,9580,8242,299,164,111,108,164,9552,64,926,964,8240,70,61,8312,69,8992,9668,9573,947,188,90,62,957,38,45,82,176,8308,917,923,177,119,954,126,57,8596,936,914,126,918,936,8805,9658,92,8729,9619,8218,185,9472,41,257,60,926,66,9619,9572,952,9619,931,926,111,8730,88,8596,171,66,64,66,9484,177,945,8805,125,64,8304,166,189,311,104,104,188,958,230,124,927,78,164,50,126,9675,123,9496,94,8593,116,8253,918,177,101,111,353,8593,121,39,65,923,179,8592,111,8310,123,8310,55,72,198,8992,72,177,8218,424,109,965,8218,63,954,955,8595,100,423,966,123,74,8747,9484,8541,166,952,66,108,917,954,9617,8532,125,96,920,967,74,9496,85,65,8776,954,9492,55,119,353,122,8311,106,83,60,73,32,932,9565,171,40,96,8805,189,921,37,105,8313,8532,33,9675,74,921,52,32,45,119,291,89,111,55,111,46,52,113,311,923,93,917,957,964,90,188,275,964,8310,947,915,926,87,956,83,42,949,92,8721,8312,82,71,937,1472,922,8540,920,8242,122,9633,106,8311,8721,8252,316,916,9484,67,92,954,8252,35,44,43,8805,966,94,947,230,923,914,9650,8801,178,74,116,8734,8993,9650,49,9632,112,8242,9484,960,932,959,9488,957,326,921,959,8800,59,915,190,921,78,8992,8594,78,172,166,8594,9553,8531,922,8312,189,8310,124,178,963,116,103,8310,63,8317,102,57,42,8304,64,72,382,189,933,964,110,182,164,316,60,80,968,8542,113,8308,8304,122,71,95,8800,68,103,9562,9472,964,8539,230,923,9496,947,74,49,923,86,74,36,82,957,64,8540,926,33,32,914,88,1472,933,59,921,167,121,9562,8747,964,9619,946,964,248,949,8308,51,957,182,81,8721,123,99,8593,934,9633,89,8470,8240,117,33,177,63,937,79,951,125,166,959,77,123,9650,78,8805,106,8734,81,954,58,63,968,382,275,102,116,8734,9565,9472,423,8317,95,39,8721,945,120,353,101,951,44,115,8260,8311,47,957,916,937,9559,8805,107,920,9668,89,316,8541,110,423,8218,382,84,291,949,116,185,118,9572,90,43,171,935,965,954,9565,8540,8242,126,8721,126,963,47,8310,968,935,89,102,951,115,955,9617,8253,8494,106,9552,424,99,46,963,61,950,8313,112,424,108,161,299,8540,59,55,55,8710,47,8730,52,9618,958,9572,914,8317,74,936,8304,109,77,42,177,8219,44,113,925,8540,55,8541,47,99,8313,8304,316,84,961,936,929,8313,353,40,42,926,9559,44,927,9496,8729,68,190,968,917,959,8308,966,8805,111,97,8540,8309,94,9559,8543,64,79,99,8252,73,123,116,185,8747,107,363,9552,8595,161,44,931,121,8597,924,177,91,66,9675,100,8747,1472,8470,8592,8309,85,968,124,964,9565,8595,38,9532,951,9660,968,44,8470,8595,8470,916,75,70,8593,45,83,53,924,932,177,8260,949,8252,80,382,59,97,959,8309,74,9668,920,8595,8539,9488,95,90,111,188,86,43,9573,115,8540,353,9632,958,916,123,59,924,124,67,67,8729,923,920,311,968,50,53,87,42,8594,66,112,8309,8309,316,96,925,44,8729,46,56,61,97,9553,8240,76,161,115,9552,935,111,968,957,67,66,117,67,955,275,100,54,9650,952,955,9650,102,917,179,929,9556,8734,8596,316,920,954,927,9619,9675,123,8710,35,966,125,84,8539,966,71,923,42,114,8776,99,933,93,924,81,8729,77,8593,9552,32,946,57,32,966,8542,945,8747,106,81,9532,953,58,92,961,188,122,176,9553,35,928,914,40,8596,363,951,91,172,8592,44,8747,41,102,44,164,955,74,67,108,8710,9,9532,964,86,960,89,8597,8992,84,934,8253,179,190,333,122,9660,60,118,161,116,9668,8532,9633,291,952,9617,960,316,248,8776,81,959,311,8539,937,9484,929,187,114,916,102,49,8240,936,179,46,166,920,69,79,8592,94,8801,8595,70,86,923,73,61,291,112,954,49,9580,8541,8540,948,76,343,58,8308,8318,111,107,50,9617,95,44,923,80,89,118,52,275,929,922,121,42,9632,79,8304,48,48,8308,311,964,9619,66,965,8260,275,966,918,9496,121,8240,109,77,121,951,948,8532,326,8313,42,57,107,103,333,927,105,125,111,9572,80,114,8240,8542,915,80,118,8219,176,8312,9496,9675,179,69,9484,8596,921,89,114,269,934,8317,927,8318,914,956,8218,959,248,9474,46,423,68,109,69,66,923,8313,171,950,9618,953,965,172,9617,46,55,49,9608,9650,45,40,8242,62,76,70,121,9492,961,8776,188,917,45,63,8308,52,89,948,164,35,97,9474,86,106,963,119,935,123,9532,8596,9484,171,8308,925,8304,96,41,916,117,9559,164,8543,961,8801,75,114,125,81,9619,8253,98,41,9608,8539,8801,187,68,101,230,81,50,45,8540,68,161,8800,960,9650,172,9660,99,933,9484,172,291,121,187,188,299,919,919,921,59,113,112,8730,363,8311,171,50,9556,9488,122,185,70,928,247,926,47,121,915,8800,66,935,9553,8304,8992,9658,967,39,9633,67,103,964,117,8252,8595,8310,952,112,58,90,33,185,945,275,122,945,100,51,955,311,86,36,920,9552,8543,124,62,247,117,8800,60,958,952,933,104,424,8800,48,37,8801,44,8308,8710,49,177,964,53,87,126,9,954,177,73,9492,9565,8805,9559,84,188,83,291,927,949,8594,915,115,53,107,954,382,343,948,8219,926,934,8747,161,167,8312,62,80,8253,937,55,8219,8800,47,247,8734,79,86,104,72,108,51,93,166,326,8318,87,8318,171,187,965,316,925,46,113,950,9556,121,35,965,8253,969,343,964,35,45,161,101,937,917,927,71,67,118,123,9572,917,9650,9488,1472,9553,8260,925,9496,9617,958,963,8532,8542,49,57,964,112,966,8539,164,126,926,81,8801,74,936,8593,8730,86,102,926,959,8801,961,37,93,963,9608,40,55,363,316,269,171,39,8304,9580,423,248,83,954,382,123,9668,124,46,935,951,167,8260,110,49,114,57,100,948,66,9675,54,8801,915,73,9573,8776,916,8531,45,8710,188,353,37,923,8531,100,9675,63,113,959,68,56,88,8804,247,958,8592,956,37,9633,311,9675,949,8308,8312,166,93,928,8311,198,91,39,8219,248,9660,8252,959,8592,125,8308,48,8596,185,39,914,968,96,99,916,55,93,9488,8594,931,353,9552,299,87,230,8593,76,69,947,66,9632,9632,33,99,125,9488,36,58,73,90,100,921,177,8470,935,69,102,935,927,9650,8800,8260,9562,326,48,96,8730,937,343,167,8776,926,79,924,84,45,343,914,171,9559,924,42,198,8801,9633,326,74,8494,8594,917,8541,78,126,106,9660,8596,959,79,8313,316,9580,105,8721,36,46,9496,115,54,78,919,45,230,9633,9633,74,85,9562,8801,44,963,182,964,88,1472,9632,963,9633,171,965,32,8304,8729,48,230,949,9572,116,9496,189,74,9553,959,83,311,919,9562,9572,8532,61,53,100,118,71,9556,9608,9619,424,9,65,8532,79,189,89,8542,176,8240,126,44,123,920,84,423,926,84,91,953,97,8308,8541,953,106,53,164,8594,914,9668,43,8801,257,9668,343,8470,926,46,177,36,84,922,8597,928,8992,198,936,8543,922,179,69,8311,90,965,66,8311,98,9472,915,40,8539,8313,118,247,949,88,8260,39,125,113,110,8470,110,94,919,8470,9618,915,9608,82,917,66,951,8541,107,44,9532,919,171,8800,116,920,275,946,188,915,8304,954,8318,83,916,958,75,57,68,164,8312,110,954,91,123,230,926,932,9573,103,8311,167,9660,8734,94,109,37,8313,8593,117,959,87,9633,958,108,8729,84,36,922,122,926,9562,190,248,8240,61,120,75,269,60,61,923,69,948,923,88,60,177,106,122,41,952,8308,8543,41,8253,106,343,932,423,424,73,9553,8734,8804,99,33,966,198,59,58,8310,85,8304,73,43,97,9619,967,9492,84,923,8310,9559,60,9668,8311,424,35,947,100,934,951,62,187,230,51,916,8242,8309,125,934,166,8310,67,926,8801,82,8304,8734,190,105,291,116,9633,188,80,121,969,9660,9618,97,182,8592,9562,9556,9484,8729,109,8804,75,67,423,111,8721,60,8540,187,35,8218,952,35,65,953,39,9553,9556,8253,9496,969,8310,925,382,8593,189,9668,65,108,8311,927,108,9632,916,9573,916,8721,73,48,107,117,8219,73,76,967,190,8531,44,9474,52,8470,959,9633,38,934,118,79,161,959,8801,333,62,179,44,8531,78,69,269,932,9632,9484,107,8313,35,36,56,964,63,100,119,65,97,114,75,914,32,53,64,269,52,161,81,103,928,74,8470,9650,926,120,9633,8219,125,92,8252,179,171,9556,8993,49,82,423,92,60,76,63,61,8309,64,958,257,44,924,9573,8593,8309,60,109,920,179,164,915,8800,9472,936,275,964,102,98,54,126,956,9492,922,92,8311,933,32,61,76,176,945,945,81,106,363,56,967,171,67,88,51,9474,921,333,955,188,104,73,56,103,72,952,62,926,9660,230,8219,954,9562,8304,915,918,947,959,190,66,125,955,189,9632,57,9472,83,72,113,8595,964,969,97,32,382,8805,926,8309,8260,8993,948,9580,8219,172,117,8308,247,41,118,8597,187,1472,89,960,166,79,9572,94,51,122,931,8747,8304,64,198,126,110,9632,113,917,74,166,8596,8593,8313,77,124,189,8776,32,958,98,961,172,82,95,84,118,935,66,423,927,8313,56,299,8776,76,8801,84,60,114,8734,40,112,51,918,8804,124,33,98,44,89,964,190,103,8470,44,46,171,70,343,8805,171,59,963,247,75,8734,44,49,63,9474,9556,167,9632,8540,90,949,948,101,72,109,91,57,43,933,8597,189,921,8494,188,9532,40,120,8729,9492,8710,93,109,86,189,8541,9474,98,52,110,8730,72,8593,9658,968,914,8308,9553,104,62,119,182,382,8776,56,954,424,921,9573,112,929,8541,52,919,126,275,8730,55,9617,45,9619,927,920,247,64,42,41,89,50,9562,125,8992,8730,188,8312,95,9552,89,967,80,275,76,75,925,115,91,8596,190,8308,8252,126,9650,101,248,1472,8260,79,917,59,924,104,967,955,90,190,68,117,931,343,8252,8304,67,316,50,8805,32,9474,923,967,9559,8304,963,9472,936,8710,9556,110,8710,8260,957,84,105,178,931,116,946,935,108,8311,8494,8312,40,931,118,958,176,8804,8593,119,8596,9552,43,188,955,230,960,916,47,952,968,45,920,8710,88,81,963,257,92,83,172,8219,8470,111,9619,120,927,9660,353,102,113,77,9675,120,177,8721,107,108,167,9,123,955,9556,965,9675,80,185,56,424,920,382,85,185,75,90,960,1472,269,44,188,326,114,8242,333,9484,933,97,46,920,37,8242,291,95,951,1472,917,43,8542,9573,8312,8594,79,109,9488,928,931,8729,9633,8252,918,44,81,8541,949,86,932,91,953,96,269,76,316,8734,66,182,36,164,291,935,929,101,956,950,9573,8597,8805,88,82,82,187,257,116,110,77,247,9562,77,924,8252,952,109,79,49,424,9668,927,9633,166,101,166,9488,8219,961,9660,176,921,115,75,8721,45,116,8260,113,257,103,46,113,59,8317,951,8993,353,934,84,167,8593,915,8317,85,299,88,51,9496,53,917,68,91,39,38,102,172,961,39,70,44,969,9562,9668,59,86,94,291,353,57,923,118,934,959,967,916,363,101,269,969,46,63,247,8776,189,935,9492,8532,919,927,316,176,424,8594,189,112,8308,51,124,8592,230,84,959,934,931,248,9492,83,58,46,966,9488,58,9,353,382,176,8804,969,119,113,189,122,958,8734,269,969,40,8721,35,969,8540,8542,185,46,117,965,9,40,954,957,8710,85,931,65,8800,8710,86,89,99,41,187,921,8260,9572,8494,8801,8543,343,68,83,964,50,63,8721,8541,9675,8801,8539,920,958,67,8597,65,8734,423,9553,35,171,424,935,50,92,107,8317,1472,61,39,925,363,954,8541,8992,61,109,8540,66,917,9472,94,178,38,291,121,921,9580,68,927,111,177,198,9618,38,1472,1472,9632,32,119,86,124,8596,8540,8800,187,9658,963,947,39,167,932,188,928,80,959,8992,56,93,43,50,65,954,106,73,960,62,933,8304,74,97,343,8804,113,954,95,75,968,172,89,90,54,66,257,32,63,71,92,64,958,8539,109,921,125,103,57,8594,177,9618,42,110,52,55,182,9658,920,963,8800,81,83,926,120,185,949,78,8542,185,8992,8219,918,9675,960,8595,929,51,99,9573,8734,8593,8730,120,8318,382,316,936,80,9562,108,40,248,933,957,125,9608,924,117,8595,921,960,257,39,915,8219,9562,925,9618,8593,37,48,75,947,42,969,945,966,100,83,953,8242,114,69,8734,47,8317,125,40,33,166,62,946,84,8312,79,198,198,93,947,957,51,936,56,8801,8729,117,198,927,108,112,8597,275,291,94,8729,60,109,108,343,8729,951,120,117,76,52,79,954,9484,311,91,8311,105,53,65,956,8218,946,76,97,9492,311,50,94,81,50,60,8532,951,9496,56,125,9633,9660,9650,953,81,125,929,69,922,112,311,920,965,950,922,9472,55,8539,179,8253,423,67,187,167,9496,119,952,918,8710,275,54,945,56,88,959,8540,48,114,56,957,81,8543,167,188,423,120,958,8747,96,9580,952,111,58,37,76,75,85,931,41,8541,50,8311,964,55,187,182,167,353,8594,43,166,182,316,95,53,64,9552,299,53,51,8309,48,8310,1472,8543,92,90,190,81,8308,291,8253,945,333,121,299,82,9562,9675,9532,8542,947,124,198,960,958,72,8218,922,937,44,9492,103,257,950,9532,111,125,966,51,59,311,424,69,107,916,32,50,80,311,9552,122,968,77,9573,946,9658,125,104,9618,9474,109,8801,77,8240,114,8734,9488,950,920,8595,40,85,103,100,51,291,176,333,82,969,8260,963,9580,9488,968,275,8596,121,8594,299,8470,8317,8311,161,9675,42,966,922,947,123,70,92,9562,969,8494,42,947,8776,112,9474,97,918,964,114,917,424,111,9,111,198,190,93,97,248,97,8240,50,917,9559,920,80,99,66,275,950,113,9632,9,100,8592,9559,89,960,57,105,931,38,9488,107,8993,917,936,8310,343,75,39,73,9559,189,198,9660,84,9556,105,8804,8539,161,914,922,88,66,93,36,8494,960,9617,914,8805,9559,326,9660,63,90,9556,115,42,83,968,9675,9532,52,965,45,107,333,97,114,178,48,957,9572,8721,424,967,38,9488,269,78,190,291,161,123,931,182,8993,948,123,49,119,9632,122,8592,9552,98,198,103,102,87,102,172,97,9573,96,120,8317,333,299,8595,178,955,69,113,66,56,40,67,62,71,80,9472,919,9,73,93,951,952,948,50,54,423,64,958,32,93,8470,63,73,8543,382,101,8776,9633,54,8804,9668,79,179,54,9617,936,964,93,107,47,8730,104,9565,58,8593,46,92,947,8543,8593,961,33,9553,946,44,423,9492,967,82,917,87,423,247,950,8470,109,112,72,177,167,86,41,60,182,299,84,87,916,8218,37,8594,920,82,126,65,275,35,44,40,117,188,8747,8593,959,9619,161,9556,8992,35,118,94,101,922,94,8260,55,179,99,111,190,39,188,9565,39,9660,9650,969,950,291,8710,51,923,8543,9633,123,40,275,86,382,248,8729,9492,961,925,9553,49,946,68,8532,257,172,932,71,8539,8776,102,9580,42,967,40,9650,120,8734,109,353,8313,36,90,117,8993,106,39,966,182,8240,112,61,56,9650,8992,52,9488,108,78,9492,952,353,363,8592,248,64,100,122,171,929,8252,101,947,107,9675,920,9608,965,81,106,187,55,316,51,8801,8541,9580,8993,958,94,8730,49,8313,8730,62,87,8242,964,98,167,8729,916,8318,1472,9572,178,111,122,343,918,8540,968,101,189,49,93,9573,185,123,927,947,45,929,9474,423,925,73,88,124,64,918,931,8240,9608,105,9658,37,182,108,121,50,42,946,8540,958,927,9553,100,58,83,61,55,964,963,84,8494,177,67,182,8805,937,123,39,54,8595,9632,8310,67,936,51,56,55,923,9660,9617,8721,9552,8311,929,257,9,8541,47,39,69,8747,172,9565,9617,115,58,937,8313,126,954,8729,8993,167,73,247,119,9668,124,43,70,9492,967,190,8532,107,179,91,48,8543,61,966,56,71,43,8260,950,424,9658,925,82,56,954,968,63,115,949,9660,925,46,326,54,104,122,95,957,167,8543,9660,914,9553,8313,63,65,64,75,123,56,8260,961,948,8318,187,125,925,8597,967,111,8595,8776,8776,8218,105,74,75,960,103,95,8494,190,43,967,9488,166,46,178,57,60,60,326,79,382,963,946,37,275,108,8308,964,8531,85,8541,9632,8318,58,9572,961,71,87,76,9633,326,934,70,923,8800,107,928,40,124,8318,36,917,98,955,104,956,8993,92,8260,959,8543,961,8532,78,925,8242,86,9474,230,198,164,179,50,960,8312,953,111,9472,915,171,56,118,179,9553,32,99,248,102,968,43,9556,65,9559,112,112,37,924,79,182,8242,919,8532,8308,8543,9488,104,9618,926,948,927,8304,95,88,9668,316,45,72,961,960,9496,52,119,94,952,423,333,61,968,958,8992,316,188,161,8309,954,102,247,115,9660,64,45,52,88,103,316,968,8260,187,8540,924,44,9496,958,52,33,9617,8531,112,71,179,35,8593,927,111,382,45,95,36,125,82,963,187,299,963,9660,9572,9562,9562,917,66,257,9650,106,299,94,8747,9488,116,9,424,956,120,925,8593,8240,382,919,54,83,925,955,166,69,50,39,52,333,9580,77,8804,316,171,959,70,87,64,957,114,121,956,8801,40,79,118,9488,8993,72,65,51,91,190,230,8532,950,8804,961,108,71,8242,969,65,9580,291,187,33,190,120,950,8539,8805,8595,8776,9632,8318,9572,95,103,8470,9650,8531,8242,171,8260,53,230,8304,316,8734,919,8311,8252,363,69,8993,8317,9617,914,9565,69,8592,931,47,8542,82,36,955,343,85,69,84,40,93,112,50,64,316,118,54,92,71,953,916,161,916,9488,49,8309,105,116,8993,89,66,177,114,8593,8470,81,76,9488,9,188,424,9492,60,124,35,9559,40,44,76,9532,8313,960,117,45,954,8253,72,37,84,914,76,8594,9658,93,9562,47,118,933,114,8595,111,33,103,956,71,122,53,9572,92,931,48,75,71,8532,95,50,932,917,8592,959,299,103,934,965,926,177,9632,55,8470,8532,8253,925,8597,936,104,8532,9632,933,83,62,178,187,9650,8592,9658,72,68,94,117,311,946,161,8539,958,123,9532,119,198,98,8539,8532,9619,230,61,333,85,9492,8318,74,919,8540,115,100,179,117,8776,8805,78,118,179,47,117,343,8804,185,98,382,382,964,124,929,933,113,123,92,8318,126,87,50,952,80,919,58,8592,102,45,933,126,187,112,919,110,959,74,9608,161,8541,917,8805,919,46,46,198,967,37,94,121,96,167,8721,8532,247,924,37,961,8543,84,8734,9658,9,182,948,311,9488,33,90,86,932,926,105,9650,60,927,83,125,55,9618,8318,8776,63,8470,924,9,945,106,8252,8318,921,55,33,89,968,171,920,924,86,363,968,76,47,72,933,35,8595,56,177,952,122,65,50,423,925,8494,59,67,937,9,47,960,8710,8470,9492,182,9553,948,91,126,967,934,914,124,99,934,69,926,311,58,67,957,915,59,935,958,113,171,353,922,9675,8309,69,87,82,8593,929,105,83,8804,58,126,79,8776,311,96,115,96,961,8532,949,936,8312,46,1472,920,118,9633,969,326,102,101,177,8805,960,190,182,8804,117,8594,33,923,86,64,52,86,960,125,119,969,106,961,161,118,914,9580,125,936,8747,951,178,59,8242,8596,269,8992,958,72,9580,56,61,8595,8532,951,935,167,914,179,952,937,59,123,8734,58,103,9552,89,119,9619,63,44,8304,86,9472,9658,8253,934,8540,37,8240,178,919,8532,922,949,60,58,43,106,933,9608,9496,958,9633,269,928,247,66,275,92,923,299,9,9608,88,123,177,166,58,111,78,185,922,961,93,8734,73,8776,33,967,54,114,53,33,953,76,9668,934,84,933,230,66,166,920,161,951,50,167,77,106,951,123,9492,9619,8543,8494,44,9488,164,67,230,32,109,164,915,9562,966,107,112,316,71,85,9553,9,41,178,99,8597,8252,8219,35,8542,9632,37,185,8747,56,958,8242,9532,79,915,927,49,90,73,9617,70,177,8218,112,931,9668,923,311,926,94,117,8219,275,952,54,8993,74,8805,8218,8597,182,8318,382,83,70,112,81,932,92,424,167,8747,8540,39,182,116,123,951,9553,8308,187,8252,9633,87,179,8240,946,97,423,75,8721,49,275,9668,931,8592,116,9580,187,8776,963,75,935,8593,948,32,121,178,8801,126,8993,8311,8313,9488,9472,9552,917,230,69,8242,70,8543,949,8318,923,77,171,66,8260,952,937,45,99,35,8721,71,937,353,86,8218,75,78,187,167,97,101,58,58,115,9580,958,952,8594,104,8308,89,363,161,275,54,8317,189,8253,8710,9650,8470,968,9559,42,8595,39,8242,8593,959,230,963,8309,164,46,8747,969,80,954,176,423,9658,960,8730,84,54,9573,8531,8800,112,91,59,966,8805,9472,950,62,83,8218,9565,8729,62,67,952,198,969,316,111,9472,8313,86,56,64,53,43,9553,81,171,9619,107,9632,116,945,969,176,945,8318,947,921,9562,9633,45,363,45,8734,161,69,40,9474,961,93,35,90,9496,71,965,923,9675,61,947,946,110,326,85,9619,9632,44,178,8992,9633,37,8242,78,8318,299,41,937,74,57,363,88,9562,60,43,188,74,9,9573,924,9496,161,81,932,8311,94,97,8539,8800,111,108,925,946,52,958,9608,946,918,9553,8541,424,8317,63,8311,124,8531,230,68,9,54,121,188,120,57,8242,8596,89,8318,269,269,8317,78,954,106,75,122,118,966,299,8729,8318,311,917,88,57,8747,61,291,960,9573,125,8721,8242,969,98,960,9492,935,914,121,99,115,182,1472,8801,38,8730,9492,257,112,98,8240,120,198,916,178,951,69,58,97,8240,9618,87,84,8595,101,933,291,917,73,917,8311,57,257,9553,82,100,52,36,56,969,9633,64,915,40,9472,115,9618,91,8721,69,80,9474,9496,926,47,966,182,8542,47,230,951,9632,55,36,8218,8542,951,8308,64,8596,257,925,103,118,924,177,954,934,59,8804,8993,928,68,113,9675,74,382,926,33,951,164,8242,9492,8597,934,97,8776,40,967,8721,97,8747,316,9472,59,46,9675,57,124,951,8542,112,103,969,948,182,9619,949,102,75,84,42,91,925,924,248,8310,9492,9618,112,9668,8470,57,124,9,9675,92,44,106,946,9650,109,114,945,922,8218,73,9573,915,9496,66,8729,81,8308,9580,198,116,275,8253,9552,957,8310,927,9484,77,8540,63,333,326,921,963,176,9675,8540,9668,316,9658,118,933,111,97,291,951,94,966,166,8253,8260,8595,35,125,922,90,923,88,41,8800,82,9532,84,78,946,343,8597,959,125,171,172,946,959,41,291,93,38,8540,37,9472,8597,269,55,363,928,928,8531,959,9492,8313,67,230,121,104,9474,66,954,8312,42,8318,8595,50,423,954,115,87,947,936,123,967,8595,79,115,969,9496,47,61,46,955,919,118,291,916,8730,53,8312,8312,104,182,932,65,8541,54,80,1472,33,9675,88,112,50,41,91,9492,8253,118,82,8304,87,35,8801,190,66,9633,85,58,8730,49,8541,164,45,69,37,964,967,45,78,117,37,32,74,9562,959,97,955,965,9559,198,126,67,915,107,62,8776,101,32,8595,8594,182,189,8543,112,353,8596,925,63,8992,77,87,933,62,95,62,8539,8252,917,915,182,946,179,100,9633,75,9562,8721,8219,119,8992,119,102,8800,41,88,49,119,8540,68,8253,47,9632,969,424,8804,77,311,247,32,124,66,954,188,8310,9488,46,91,115,316,248,967,96,9573,932,41,82,316,82,230,9617,8260,8539,949,917,275,123,114,353,954,961,99,8318,8747,79,966,41,37,8317,126,161,8310,8218,84,9532,98,79,104,52,103,66,926,38,929,923,299,9488,9553,955,66,167,936,41,72,86,9484,99,230,38,74,105,52,8592,56,9474,45,964,188,8805,9553,32,424,257,363,121,9552,93,92,92,8494,107,119,955,9532,118,8801,923,921,8593,965,88,9608,8801,38,8260,49,967,8594,9565,56,43,8218,915,961,122,51,176,9474,56,950,954,9474,107,77,8539,946,80,9675,964,99,928,8318,45,937,83,89,126,53,326,58,40,948,311,8805,8542,956,934,37,171,963,928,950,1472,48,43,969,934,44,949,968,62,924,51,91,59,8992,326,353,9553,89,102,39,9580,8252,8311,182,8253,934,113,917,118,8592,8539,120,9619,47,87,118,179,102,124,112,45,9,925,79,947,8219,956,8532,185,40,925,921,116,934,164,125,9619,921,171,932,45,51,8721,953,961,55,116,84,171,178,965,311,91,126,126,9565,8730,8595,8543,66,85,97,8593,61,167,106,918,966,8541,8805,948,9484,120,68,948,949,185,125,8308,72,110,75,8309,8541,291,423,921,948,968,99,9619,915,75,8597,8730,98,353,946,947,51,9484,326,85,248,8747,953,70,113,969,927,230,76,64,111,42,49,967,90,8800,914,8730,38,166,76,54,107,8541,93,8776,51,922,86,177,57,935,946,99,936,926,8308,102,9617,8592,85,9553,9484,8592,60,964,8729,73,88,916,74,934,958,56,957,8253,8776,8730,920,97,8240,8218,185,99,95,969,8218,8317,927,177,959,32,46,914,248,109,99,95,64,248,291,121,98,8734,77,9619,945,8729,964,115,8304,73,8242,8240,44,8531,8253,8541,90,9618,8541,41,172,77,95,969,93,185,956,58,9565,8596,93,9617,93,326,8800,952,67,77,9608,9632,8730,948,9474,164,959,188,9532,8311,424,8540,8729,103,424,8260,924,93,188,424,75,126,8993,382,106,9562,59,85,100,8804,8710,926,937,91,8311,106,960,105,8242,9488,275,952,9474,969,8539,37,951,71,8593,97,182,107,8318,926,86,926,83,311,38,88,39,933,60,32,424,423,8242,108,96,8804,914,275,110,316,8531,111,8543,9553,80,948,89,57,934,957,8252,9484,177,275,52,39,37,67,115,123,926,9556,68,37,124,9492,967,119,9573,89,8595,965,8710,8304,948,108,76,925,8218,106,299,9556,69,316,74,8993,914,83,47,35,9474,8317,424,54,9658,8308,9,363,198,8993,104,8219,9618,46,8218,8595,115,8710,8776,8532,956,9562,77,95,9552,333,8304,47,9496,257,45,8595,62,291,117,75,8804,190,927,8242,919,53,966,8542,122,99,8494,32,110,102,343,112,948,9618,106,63,947,8992,37,929,8543,103,35,932,178,47,275,69,949,954,65,963,164,275,36,48,90,55,9556,8993,8309,424,8541,8593,189,9650,949,8540,959,959,291,8311,106,45,954,182,921,190,8317,167,9632,8804,8313,187,85,916,93,112,56,950,94,8993,8992,60,190,44,8993,923,924,8304,8531,969,9562,956,8242,105,952,967,1472,92,59,95,117,8804,248,185,121,8993,1472,311,931,8710,1472,64,71,99,954,935,177,164,353,101,100,9496,8776,61,71,8596,81,61,8801,926,105,8304,125,62,9660,55,8219,48,963,122,161,8470,9559,118,8242,9650,9484,95,9675,83,316,54,8218,8313,167,114,161,9552,8260,68,116,934,9553,9660,922,190,9565,333,118,8310,61,8801,90,38,102,63,9668,922,9618,51,44,382,8710,275,9572,9573,198,8594,74,333,118,45,933,945,8597,110,190,87,8541,316,9660,55,8260,316,8594,961,78,96,67,1472,921,928,68,8532,61,929,8993,40,247,176,119,115,967,955,9668,172,78,166,957,8253,916,247,62,929,35,9619,68,62,43,275,299,63,66,8312,50,922,8253,79,71,8730,969,928,8311,80,423,8218,945,98,9492,959,926,53,65,100,8532,247,927,179,50,275,961,8494,90,35,50,948,35,9650,8800,230,8311,62,8800,8318,52,922,423,8776,8729,67,86,9617,75,9496,80,8992,9492,8252,8541,60,89,969,914,8747,118,114,8540,80,8801,46,8543,120,423,8531,96,919,91,68,97,161,424,69,8311,9658,9472,53,9553,75,98,955,8805,9660,105,8734,924,161,36,8253,121,96,82,8219,87,63,924,9618,9675,961,58,176,75,8317,80,363,8532,97,9556,120,61,39,967,963,8595,947,9492,8730,86,8252,953,121,8594,8805,957,59,299,8531,948,8721,92,43,118,8219,67,9488,967,96,54,916,119,111,178,198,91,101,72,291,955,188,946,8309,9675,8318,915,929,8597,189,925,8594,104,954,9617,116,921,8313,311,82,958,179,923,97,8312,58,120,55,8595,103,9660,8800,916,114,116,182,9559,105,931,969,945,198,33,91,8532,120,945,77,116,959,41,916,113,70,966,167,8304,8539,64,316,112,39,959,77,423,67,45,8595,8218,299,172,936,98,77,92,8540,8304,8805,40,8310,928,8494,182,963,9552,9562,9632,56,8494,8218,176,71,79,920,299,9565,8242,8219,92,8317,248,936,8596,929,71,125,958,8540,8710,8531,299,1472,9660,9618,93,89,177,8593,954,9572,9,189,107,8531,9562,8470,114,77,89,382,947,59,8734,8992,70,929,8312,123,275,965,9565,86,926,8804,931,9660,93,946,164,95,949,9660,189,89,74,112,185,176,275,326,423,61,36,8805,925,93,9496,8593,8805,927,299,8992,9660,8309,37,89,247,84,936,187,964,9608,82,917,107,39,916,115,8310,56,101,119,8541,8730,79,92,77,326,8721,8310,95,185,97,98,114,84,8734,105,8260,41,65,101,110,9484,8721,8309,8308,78,9484,932,63,918,64,928,166,53,248,33,936,291,106,933,8801,9650,56,78,8260,107,8594,96,189,48,81,123,921,8317,40,44,8801,47,948,123,326,8747,49,96,8593,952,946,116,9658,9552,920,110,9617,382,8539,190,269,57,55,424,120,333,50,932,41,9573,75,45,38,113,74,69,198,171,9618,959,79,59,114,949,105,8240,8539,58,68,928,178,9675,8539,54,382,8596,56,67,9658,333,8313,929,9580,8311,8253,40,9580,956,58,960,178,77,8734,118,87,77,99,937,88,106,102,110,92,161,935,179,311,97,8304,947,343,43,8312,945,123,198,9496,121,9660,9618,60,964,115,9617,363,91,190,917,9472,63,8539,8596,9492,9668,299,61,914,50,964,166,188,9617,65,167,84,94,82,919,8710,8592,9660,9633,955,117,112,39,9608,963,947,9565,67,929,924,299,35,937,61,291,8253,945,124,8540,83,73,311,63,120,9572,42,926,363,110,926,9660,32,8596,925,110,9573,9675,85,123,66,9484,107,915,925,8470,9633,95,333,920,122,257,8710,75,922,92,423,914,333,182,80,57,965,9580,80,299,9553,916,117,9492,969,9619,918,32,9472,945,343,32,8597,9553,9658,8253,8309,167,8801,86,914,954,88,179,79,952,8800,928,120,920,161,8710,965,80,90,57,958,9660,100,47,964,9632,46,101,925,164,188,49,88,9618,8734,8309,8710,8310,71,924,105,8710,8992,59,43,69,122,88,9580,9618,923,9668,48,966,299,115,75,920,111,9496,111,920,57,96,922,117,299,166,311,8313,117,343,931,84,55,80,9562,955,179,9580,8240,97,8539,55,948,926,8539,75,9488,964,8260,8240,8801,937,188,190,8800,189,945,48,230,76,8597,44,9660,424,423,936,8541,1472,8309,9660,928,248,9619,115,90,275,188,172,102,52,9572,8531,353,58,8594,966,967,166,38,8309,8312,8242,97,161,122,32,120,87,8219,179,109,47,91,110,935,35,80,8253,98,85,9580,8540,8710,955,925,935,177,933,8593,88,90,8218,119,84,9650,36,8219,71,423,91,177,961,8595,161,954,41,9632,8747,178,37,953,8309,97,8539,69,85,8242,248,8593,9668,190,91,46,8804,76,8805,9484,968,8312,38,923,61,8218,123,45,70,269,9608,230,64,198,48,960,50,954,936,8317,9675,8318,41,48,49,198,110,177,954,8240,8240,9668,423,185,9552,185,8317,8596,957,9552,9633,8532,124,8805,951,8219,110,73,964,65,931,179,8252,956,8240,9472,8318,49,326,40,171,9617,44,957,919,955,96,8219,8800,190,188,920,88,93,8253,72,44,91,45,60,69,46,961,960,39,76,179,117,966,9660,41,9,9496,33,8532,956,9496,9580,59,921,968,52,87,968,9573,103,164,90,75,9474,8318,8776,73,9618,33,299,299,955,952,76,8310,248,8800,8494,916,9553,9618,9559,8242,9660,74,110,916,36,36,915,9565,918,949,97,964,963,80,8312,8252,8543,81,953,46,88,166,8470,8747,93,952,126,97,299,44,112,55,33,947,9474,65,74,185,198,58,9633,178,946,8240,8597,48,75,42,946,8801,70,918,9668,88,9619,230,9553,8593,89,951,928,109,89,62,178,79,198,8539,43,161,167,67,8242,9619,316,48,182,100,8992,62,960,32,72,247,353,64,93,964,948,915,9492,8540,8219,8541,8252,955,167,172,8304,8218,918,382,920,8310,8776,121,8592,179,948,38,8304,966,109,8734,91,9650,67,57,919,919,9562,922,316,171,104,78,92,185,86,969,918,50,953,932,967,951,66,122,9573,9608,946,9565,9562,9618,8734,56,171,39,8219,177,8242,73,120,9573,8729,62,9573,8310,8242,8805,62,927,44,81,94,69,52,922,101,104,9619,89,32,117,257,920,9573,920,923,93,71,921,961,8317,8747,101,64,99,8309,8219,9617,8729,84,964,9580,106,95,9565,38,949,316,8318,8710,35,70,95,9580,936,9553,198,116,8470,8596,60,8804,98,8801,189,122,54,110,121,9532,101,164,8218,9650,363,172,98,107,9496,172,946,40,77,8531,85,61,45,8494,382,9658,122,56,927,106,933,954,8730,9532,106,96,112,54,98,101,41,8309,915,75,8721,932,62,9632,363,111,8242,92,8218,8218,101,928,69,423,57,37,8710,72,42,8308,52,75,926,948,45,111,99,9617,934,257,934,125,198,102,8801,958,9633,920,106,82,928,8992,928,110,954,172,8993,190,172,8805,343,924,88,8311,9572,187,98,103,9552,51,73,102,105,8805,71,8541,8804,8800,343,914,299,269,58,275,164,91,51,8313,423,87,343,953,63,8542,77,8313,79,8801,918,8240,8543,8312,96,937,914,40,120,90,55,52,35,8541,78,299,52,8219,84,37,424,41,8253,8532,247,125,8313,8311,67,230,8540,86,8593,179,71,172,945,88,99,9668,8595,122,951,8541,8540,9658,8710,353,49,117,85,68,61,73,299,84,79,8309,53,71,44,8734,8531,914,58,9565,112,9580,8540,63,9553,107,88,8800,68,96,934,172,8992,9492,85,8992,43,954,8541,9619,8318,49,933,164,363,87,8311,8543,955,9553,51,8532,118,927,8311,9633,257,343,82,967,9668,946,106,8312,916,101,9492,78,915,8252,965,171,42,927,917,110,8218,8308,187,922,363,969,108,81,9,104,9608,9675,950,311,100,102,123,1472,967,9580,929,8804,919,47,326,76,182,275,85,934,343,110,113,69,70,951,9492,56,124,59,916,9650,423,918,185,917,9488,98,172,9562,8312,39,8260,198,964,8308,8800,9572,918,928,55,9565,59,75,114,172,80,113,9496,74,946,9580,126,9553,110,927,96,9484,63,124,54,8242,951,967,926,8801,248,966,9572,87,8531,182,924,9474,8318,92,9572,67,353,8597,8543,8242,100,8470,66,49,42,118,95,100,123,198,105,188,95,98,248,966,8805,9,917,914,917,77,8313,8253,965,363,230,104,87,62,120,40,8218,8242,8494,9633,9580,67,69,101,83,311,916,333,9559,9484,8747,33,39,45,123,960,8310,968,45,8747,9474,57,102,190,8309,45,333,105,120,63,959,8219,70,8805,8531,68,50,957,44,9618,8260,9668,925,97,9618,114,8312,8531,311,89,187,967,8494,929,45,101,81,187,48,948,89,269,8597,961,52,948,52,126,925,122,9633,919,105,8311,56,8470,969,8310,247,953,125,9618,925,424,63,9492,9553,177,50,103,9565,8318,959,931,100,87,316,967,919,172,92,9565,8312,927,79,968,8318,8308,916,8260,932,920,9484,37,8801,299,80,81,9617,189,93,333,53,97,102,964,9608,43,44,957,57,9660,921,8776,9660,919,92,316,424,9488,8993,119,103,167,106,9,37,46,257,230,9492,8242,53,9562,94,915,8593,8993,935,8747,80,8710,72,8710,8776,8776,926,122,179,8470,9632,8747,177,914,179,8318,947,110,166,9532,121,922,920,8805,59,922,67,166,39,343,96,954,8313,935,423,947,80,100,947,83,109,965,8313,9675,924,9660,115,8494,311,40,78,8312,952,968,113,9632,65,63,9496,9633,60,8304,198,956,8747,74,9660,9633,925,40,68,124,8800,8311,105,914,8540,8318,189,176,87,107,76,161,9556,47,8540,8721,8308,951,353,9675,8540,961,9552,63,9474,9633,113,166,38,9553,968,299,945,177,172,122,178,8218,73,363,101,177,947,32,9572,8218,103,8721,124,59,93,94,77,9484,8721,54,269,9580,925,8309,8734,8594,96,948,935,39,110,76,9492,38,8494,110,122,9492,8540,33,40,932,97,9,353,171,47,919,921,70,8592,920,8308,116,40,926,66,9488,947,8592,9532,32,954,917,68,921,8804,8710,93,8317,9580,917,106,87,61,64,937,8721,248,9472,946,9492,8308,113,9658,61,9552,80,8597,84,112,9484,316,9565,8242,50,40,326,9552,179,41,920,164,189,9556,926,951,257,956,179,98,8593,343,9650,8992,9,38,190,969,92,37,9668,9496,248,9608,32,32,923,9552,43,9573,42,74,936,53,70,924,124,56,187,64,122,959,914,198,81,36,8260,117,51,257,8260,87,42,269,9573,100,190,126,8313,89,125,929,9562,8252,94,954,41,9618,424,8494,107,9608,123,8747,8311,110,934,69,9562,103,46,166,69,8240,9562,102,8592,99,87,956,311,178,161,954,8318,9668,187,954,915,51,64,167,105,75,9619,84,8593,9668,35,178,91,66,112,8730,33,9668,965,177,171,954,9633,8494,382,92,85,917,8540,8311,110,956,57,922,52,49,8310,46,9484,9484,9675,83,8805,8541,8308,968,949,8310,62,43,8531,8309,928,928,78,9556,9617,8592,64,914,36,43,914,915,37,269,81,9633,945,76,956,8993,106,8308,924,56,8240,118,57,125,52,9562,8253,316,423,48,81,353,9565,55,8730,94,187,9660,52,343,73,86,190,177,326,967,102,8253,928,9556,41,960,961,164,166,103,198,275,8317,929,105,937,32,8313,8747,95,36,9492,923,182,949,9660,106,92,113,932,49,81,933,87,9618,8734,936,44,954,9556,39,269,9572,106,257,39,57,51,69,121,423,120,8721,73,8531,8804,9472,960,172,8252,960,9488,8304,8805,8595,117,9572,59,945,965,8710,960,178,9668,55,94,9553,961,951,353,8805,119,424,103,343,62,120,117,189,33,326,97,929,89,117,8734,49,33,178,81,950,39,931,963,109,72,964,353,93,275,171,109,87,177,106,8532,955,103,48,969,40,8539,93,122,50,8593,934,928,96,8240,953,54,108,8594,966,946,36,964,9472,952,291,88,8541,269,9552,953,120,8240,969,291,915,299,247,110,960,9633,102,8532,8219,8317,114,8592,8242,109,9572,8219,969,61,423,176,65,67,9572,1472,923,953,95,78,8470,955,59,8734,87,121,1472,9474,920,124,60,965,9474,269,952,230,931,966,96,107,99,95,126,9573,967,9559,946,86,37,9618,56,32,125,87,32,35,96,9556,105,47,934,8304,95,8308,161,343,187,119,39,104,9565,172,950,950,104,968,8734,166,8801,9565,90,959,952,32,8318,54,248,117,953,934,8240,8594,9618,69,248,71,96,964,935,105,953,9472,8317,8730,9552,931,91,948,8805,75,9565,967,40,9484,9496,99,8242,919,931,38,8313,949,68,41,123,8721,8311,958,9472,182,114,916,111,8260,947,9496,36,8734,88,963,108,114,8801,954,960,9660,109,937,41,90,916,126,79,125,9617,87,945,80,9617,107,8310,67,8721,952,109,8747,948,916,423,73,185,161,924,9552,121,382,8311,964,125,92,9632,8729,8240,109,8219,102,84,950,914,9617,8730,9496,8597,68,47,178,946,45,8260,8992,62,65,955,76,94,112,916,945,74,121,187,114,9633,8318,8470,49,93,172,36,50,120,178,9492,915,51,9492,50,955,104,8776,74,106,423,333,102,955,917,85,965,8595,110,933,950,8312,937,92,111,9562,9,79,73,382,8260,8494,8594,923,106,353,248,937,178,43,8252,113,50,248,230,969,90,120,8729,110,95,8804,99,8304,8730,9496,48,937,963,952,113,8543,79,916,8992,959,8539,9562,74,75,8531,951,316,9496,8721,79,9532,81,9573,956,9496,8804,8539,166,967,916,69,104,86,9484,48,8993,423,957,423,382,963,9496,100,8721,103,248,8317,122,50,58,62,952,230,68,275,89,924,51,920,8804,66,57,78,122,110,106,87,931,934,96,423,8734,8540,9650,164,914,8218,91,8312,963,91,37,113,178,8804,67,8494,8597,9474,8594,9552,111,113,917,917,8543,9556,166,8592,115,103,959,269,8710,933,77,8531,108,61,8252,925,103,8218,363,8318,929,8310,9492,966,79,198,105,9617,9472,198,9608,80,8219,343,8252,114,161,8304,123,423,44,187,9660,9619,45,164,950,48,117,37,9633,8594,920,9650,966,953,112,60,56,947,9632,9632,187,424,48,257,961,959,951,112,62,57,109,9488,8531,77,9608,963,115,950,84,108,9650,269,8597,951,8747,230,931,96,9559,326,37,921,39,188,84,110,8317,164,53,105,382,9632,9660,353,9675,103,8734,954,9632,8260,89,8532,920,167,121,8540,9660,9573,172,91,967,950,952,951,9573,956,423,164,9608,73,44,953,423,311,92,949,40,185,916,9660,8311,952,9619,9,915,8800,69,74,8801,99,8252,43,106,8312,947,112,966,326,8317,9562,8309,8800,66,311,71,945,69,46,927,62,9532,333,90,8253,114,182,915,936,8730,8597,44,61,8596,8540,948,948,8721,8470,947,51,949,32,9474,326,947,8776,79,122,89,94,41,8313,67,933,91,8242,73,8242,9572,190,189,122,179,8592,8240,86,8710,116,8800,967,920,248,8542,47,102,9618,8310,922,42,958,101,957,8252,8260,275,97,9618,928,190,928,123,80,85,934,60,8310,9496,935,8304,291,920,9532,311,40,423,914,424,67,8730,8805,8594,9632,9556,117,8710,70,9532,104,8220,353,953,959,58,124,79,961,247,9,41,8804,105,950,343,111,102,126,71,248,56,59,920,166,9565,9488,64,257,37,71,88,965,77,955,9496,8729,311,111,969,945,917,8805,9650,53,115,8494,189,1472,118,188,9580,230,52,952,57,88,71,8993,921,918,117,926,80,83,955,8311,55,8540,179,918,8721,922,935,188,921,8252,8594,96,8317,80,936,58,948,90,167,8729,9619,171,959,8721,187,951,64,108,9552,291,126,424,116,121,172,56,915,190,46,8311,102,93,108,933,172,108,63,8309,951,8993,48,915,247,124,176,9619,56,9496,93,965,176,39,968,247,363,55,178,299,72,248,32,8318,112,8531,87,945,9632,122,926,185,8594,316,115,230,90,188,934,925,53,46,97,9572,967,113,105,8541,8993,8592,39,92,107,91,951,9552,8252,257,918,75,172,99,167,311,8317,946,8532,9552,316,33,79,51,9650,8312,9668,45,8710,924,104,83,9618,291,103,920,9675,957,8800,79,109,86,39,9553,9617,8747,954,914,172,269,164,76,8541,8218,85,189,8240,92,190,190,9617,8747,917,9573,424,9532,75,931,187,36,73,105,9488,9484,83,119,98,8595,921,40,59,958,957,1472,9619,934,9618,917,121,951,9474,1472,76,9658,164,935,56,176,8470,73,934,98,93,9484,9472,9488,8308,955,118,59,190,9556,43,47,935,44,9488,9532,189,8747,96,57,187,921,8310,8592,60,961,103,9556,920,299,91,63,935,423,969,931,9619,343,40,46,63,926,9573,80,8312,198,382,72,9474,8531,8804,9562,299,9496,8313,117,126,164,178,964,106,9565,8747,94,55,8729,951,48,1472,119,926,100,8595,8313,52,182,950,961,248,9580,49,8804,8532,64,92,71,926,57,343,88,950,190,8776,8308,115,928,111,275,72,316,182,951,161,104,316,326,8730,333,961,113,51,954,84,9496,87,125,39,945,9632,1472,112,299,9658,97,965,177,9618,953,9488,964,933,9618,8541,8318,9496,8309,8993,89,275,98,65,8531,80,8596,8310,84,92,8543,8805,931,9552,424,931,961,45,75,95,41,954,948,8543,8541,74,8313,77,961,59,922,8542,172,75,8313,189,63,248,104,123,120,9496,72,950,926,58,112,122,71,166,956,926,73,76,959,77,123,960,65,9559,49,969,967,9488,8805,9608,102,118,63,9559,9484,8993,189,9565,8596,69,382,8218,9474,126,423,81,185,920,8540,167,111,966,9658,65,424,923,9675,35,343,8730,9484,178,248,9496,8805,8219,1472,35,40,8240,9556,177,935,114,110,75,91,1472,956,164,38,122,8216,111,53,9472,114,8721,34,45,43,60,62,46,8221,123,275,59,343,125,111,34,291,35,291,8312,424,74,917,92,102,9580,45,8308,8597,920,953,80,914,190,71,182,91,125,8542,9632,88,8729,954,917,966,9632,51,85,126,326,353,299,85,9580,8595,59,87,8992,74,105,96,93,164,423,9565,48,188,166,8540,951,111,949,8801,179,966,125,185,8594,171,960,9556,932,248,951,87,98,61,49,56,63,161,9675,922,9488,32,921,8594,100,914,45,107,8993,964,922,41,921,114,113,121,164,9472,959,923,8494,8308,185,36,126,100,257,9492,9,43,90,343,8494,8531,299,9633,90,8311,9484,248,97,937,9484,948,98,9562,959,188,936,42,99,9472,916,8734,172,275,74,90,363,9472,937,113,9496,8253,43,179,8543,182,8543,8253,172,98,109,967,182,9573,9559,9484,189,37,291,73,333,125,8542,124,187,178,934,125,50,957,935,8311,104,9572,46,8539,107,41,968,933,8539,961,80,177,8595,42,72,102,299,8542,947,78,9632,90,382,8310,69,952,99,8542,969,78,113,38,114,179,8540,927,230,188,937,8318,106,100,99,8310,8310,9565,920,423,9668,961,41,58,9618,189,113,50,121,9552,64,112,8993,109,948,185,424,49,8218,43,8540,960,8242,8721,9532,9617,33,48,8805,923,55,110,68,179,326,8304,64,100,311,8992,936,257,116,54,291,9658,9532,80,62,8539,110,954,124,8592,936,311,247,103,50,423,179,51,42,8734,33,100,51,35,75,89,8594,9650,35,8218,8318,117,8993,123,8993,87,952,8805,8539,81,9,9559,9,55,8531,8595,80,176,8730,914,68,9532,8308,9556,8308,917,968,176,9580,959,121,126,958,966,9668,8593,957,190,8596,44,311,39,9658,58,9668,928,8242,60,257,8312,8219,8597,98,937,958,918,40,188,73,88,104,9580,9618,9559,955,187,936,102,46,54,123,53,167,8309,92,8494,8219,423,382,9618,74,968,82,8801,935,915,79,75,961,111,949,9632,8310,178,126,8532,8710,949,8730,928,55,8318,424,311,57,9633,8593,248,161,952,56,115,927,9650,93,47,316,965,60,8260,957,966,87,343,9668,62,116,113,73,8532,42,8776,933,969,919,947,78,178,918,113,927,102,9496,8317,167,947,45,87,9668,949,9532,126,9552,929,47,80,9562,61,951,8543,8730,954,166,77,99,8734,67,8800,76,190,120,8312,363,94,179,8801,8801,167,96,8313,106,8592,964,966,161,947,914,8252,72,9552,969,925,9472,934,8992,64,964,957,65,9572,299,9532,57,9617,93,961,9562,81,62,969,921,9565,97,188,50,915,8597,9532,963,179,41,9675,326,934,275,8801,68,9532,61,68,109,123,291,8734,46,934,124,108,8592,423,932,56,94,89,118,126,9488,9492,77,41,84,8317,8721,316,41,8531,100,126,8311,9668,923,54,94,8541,72,230,105,8734,1472,275,95,936,958,343,9608,9492,9632,922,8260,9552,114,929,49,363,925,933,955,8776,326,46,45,123,106,86,70,121,33,8313,954,57,107,934,948,8308,95,47,114,9556,8543,961,37,247,967,8470,9484,964,949,9580,8594,113,47,423,916,9553,959,60,8721,423,952,36,957,8800,8730,114,176,8532,8710,8805,89,108,230,58,9472,61,950,82,188,247,90,954,98,9572,247,963,36,311,966,112,353,96,48,8597,8730,123,948,42,9553,46,75,73,117,124,98,8721,43,916,8992,123,931,44,959,80,88,52,8470,91,70,91,8531,8531,957,1472,67,179,198,968,40,9608,9617,120,120,182,925,75,49,247,948,116,8592,9532,9472,9488,8596,311,52,967,968,59,71,946,74,9474,8309,945,247,954,948,8539,123,40,171,8242,70,52,8800,952,9668,57,53,9492,40,93,914,9532,125,9472,96,49,171,1472,8310,922,8595,9650,269,38,927,113,935,182,54,9660,56,55,36,925,56,68,66,89,96,965,111,947,123,114,9562,9608,9492,8253,104,968,928,58,97,76,968,919,8993,8804,104,924,8494,9552,93,952,84,8992,73,9472,71,935,343,8532,40,9556,8542,72,9660,93,937,65,107,9675,382,69,929,121,8542,42,120,8218,189,9668,47,9559,8543,914,37,70,43,113,53,311,937,44,9472,8597,105,269,8494,92,99,933,917,38,54,8532,75,121,8531,1472,55,8800,86,8310,119,105,95,88,99,38,9556,120,42,113,57,54,8218,948,9632,299,8747,9488,8595,56,8543,88,326,44,299,9472,8260,8734,955,99,74,959,70,951,9619,247,32,8317,958,164,177,124,8308,112,953,9562,9580,8219,105,8721,8595,74,63,924,61,198,38,326,8747,9488,424,918,93,61,9484,86,1472,123,40,63,99,96,967,8730,9617,51,8721,119,423,166,113,126,8242,167,111,8747,90,8242,72,66,8304,423,8734,110,291,116,8317,8776,928,76,8312,8992,9617,91,64,50,48,8747,8804,82,8595,8993,185,8993,269,9573,960,8311,8216,111}]
```

Permalink makes the post too long, but [here](https://mathics.angusgriffith.com/)'s a pretty good site to try it online.

#### **Let's keep things ASCII friendly, yeah?**

Answer (score 0):

## 9. [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 372 bytes (UTF-8)

```
욑㐇䐇嬈㐇㐇㐇㑸吗箝셫籲権엵뀕㙧碈竝퍰ꬠ䶛繒蔟쨶꧹趇싐灟쵎쒨걿䈷掴샬无㹶誅聉뺄ﱖ瑊깛떘꙱읇䛪팘킁焲륐䠢峘ꫛ莲뤝轂灏襩蛂虥襳뙫ꇵ屡撐餼ךּ窬趋ꢙ數晊琣鿙靻췩阻佘蹷䂦꨻㛞䇎ꗕ｡쾜赳꾲ꓠ㥌䴸蠼更䐾䥛䤓䡓餃稖蹽彻埜망䡎闞䫹轤我듋
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.3/JstxGWT.html?code=7JqR74ON45CH5JCH5ayI45CH45CH45CH45G45ZCX566d7IWr57Gy8KStr%24aoqeyXteuAleOZp%24eiiPCQpJXnq53wppSt7Y2w6qyg5Lab8KSbtOe5kuiUn_Cli5busIDsqLbqp7notofwkJ6j8KaEv%24yLkOeBn%24y1juySqOqxv%24SIt%24aOtOyDrPCQorfuv7Dml6DjubbukoLoqoXogYnruoTvsZbnkYrquZvrlpjqmbHsnYfkm6rtjJjtgoHnhLLrpZDkoKLwpoaA5bOY6qub6I6y66Sd6L2C8JGGr%24eBj_Cmnq7opanom4LomaXopbPvmLPrmavqh7XwpI2O8JGdqOWxoeaSkOmkvPCktr3vrLrnqqzotovwkKWB6qKZ5pW48JCDkOaZiu6nhOeQo_CQtYPpv5npnbvst6npmLvkvZjoubfuhobkgqbwppaA6qi745ue8JCkmvCluoDkh47ulKzwkZut75%24t6peV772h8KWMrey%24nO6Tl%24i1s%24q%24suqToPClgqXjpYzktLjumIjooLzmm7TvnpnkkL7kpZvwkIyQ5KST8KS2i%24Shk_ClvrbppIPwpLqw56iW6Lm95b275Z%24c8JGXhOunneShjvCRjpbpl57wpayO5Ku56L2k7oS28KWquPCmop_miJHrk4s%3D)

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

## 11. [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org), 1000 bytes

```ruby
puts "丟뫉뚑뫸꾍먹겇멉겇멚뢈먹겇먹겇먹겇먹궸멙겗멺몝뫈놫멻궲묊낭뛾늨뚞뢗띞란땞꾙뙾뎢뒏겐뙉뇧뚹맰뙩낭뫘린몪뢠멋늛묊낛띎뎹딮뒔뗿겥뒹닮뜈곬뚋닪뙻뗨띨돰딉몣묊늄럾뢋딎뎁뗾뢵듮뢒뚎뚱럾낈띾늎띎뢃뛏겐똫돮럻곦땺곣랛닮딨껨뚨뇨되뗫램냯뜙닧딘뛪랙럫땩듪떛귬뗘돤떺뛭듉듭됨귧둋껫뙙곤똊껰뙨늀멛꾘몪랛몈몲몺낝몋릂묉궆뛾뎁듿겦뗪뫨뙚뗨떸껨떚뇨뙛꿯떋꿫떚럪둻뇰뙈릎묉궝뚎놱똞늒딎떤럏겤띫맯뛋뛧뚪루띨런딊놁몪꺙멩놸묉것딎늙뒮몧둎뎐똿겐띘꿩럹뗩뗛러띺뗩떋럤럙듨랛돮둨다됪닰뙩늀몪뒻먹랞묉겤떯겥램곤둸뫮땊룰딙랭뫹뮭목뎕뫻릡묊놌뛞뢾뗎몓땾뒵뜾뚾뜮뚓똏겥됪뇣뙘룤띋듮떈듨똋룦떻냯뗩뗤딋뫤뙙런딈뢐멊낓묊낶뒾낡딿겥럫닩뙈꿰뙋뚰멺뒖몋떽멛릻멙뮜묉궗둎랧뗞낡듯겑듩닩땹뫰뙚뢎멊랹몋릤뫨낶묊놪랏겦똩믦뒉귫딸밋"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZPLkptWFEV/JeU/S3maQSp2BpnZ3Sk9uAmSAPEUECMF8VAjWV3ulkQF/UxGd31E51zKo0yoW1D37LPX3rz/5bcPH3/86e3t518/fvjh3b@XnHZOvKK96OFPqqs@T6nn4zOmmH1/87/ny4U60ueA@kaT0s6YtNS9fjlzsHh4IhmwKuKMIiDNyD6xzvQQEQ3YBc5Cn5dEc6Z74iv7E1FtbrUh5YmmofiLWmEl47SE1Ma@4nU4HsFdn//GuaI6NjP9fCBWqIaoJ6hIKxYnvDnN1ty1ficfKBSeTPhMIOdvuB2FQ2wTfzVfH2aksq1tVIpHknG3sGXRkff6uWR9089bssQoepXuxVfFtGIZErRkFY9HNhFqjxeSNGQRecu6xm3wE/16IAhZ7PBvJE@4c9wnlpV@3bNSum@JIv28I7R0LxwqrE/UiR5Cw0FEmxnNmebGQ0qjKB84zPXLxBAWR67QKAka2oooNgT8i9nQj82GUaLvR3yl7615kzeseqaiMqO0xzmp4TD5SphhOYaSvyMXAjvSlv2RRJFIRg3bkW0ubC0mn2U3fYuoayYXM@f8aO5aEU5HI76EtjC8G5JpqO81@ZWgJkjID6Q3c/YVuWhFuJWxKbRXFWrHskGNfRAOQsDppW9k2agiDI8m/awyxFYX2o61xVa2isikP1e6J5oae03bU34xHZj8QSI9HAhsGpf1gPONzUA8sOmIXcKFmSm60y1RyFa8K1MSf2Z2CxXbEr83KRsLOzxFu5PURhoziiW1tNQdu/qCI436gje2VGqgaqGt7@JIEZ/M/@L4Jkf/H0mZspf/iG4zZhEYbtmeIDMTXHG6wq3NhPWV9mTyLWyjlV3HJuxM6KJoPEpVFqYJYc2xxJnr1xbvwkm9e3v7Dw)

Comment: This looks like 1000 bytes. Why do you have 10^10^1000?

Comment: @mbomb007 Spaces filled after code

Random bonus for next player

Comment: Your TIO link doesn't have that as the code, nor does your post. Don't cheat. Nobody wants you to cheat the scoring system

Comment: Are you saying there should be spaces padding the answer at the end to make this 10^10^1000 bytes?

Comment: @mbomb007 Just to show the scoring is not good enough. Score doesn't go to me

Comment: No one can even get the bonus because it's impossible to print 10^10^1000 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

### 14. C++ (1252 bytes)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;
int main(){std::cout<<"$><<\"Fb[\"+'泫Aѹ୽Ñ຃Á຃°ʂÑ຃Ñ຃Ñ຃Ñ൒±๳mBय़൘\0੝ЌࡢѬɳάΊ֬ୱҌݨٻ๺ӁणёĚҡ੝2Ś`ɪ¿࡯\0੯μݑלٶԋ๥ّࠜЂพѿࠠҏԢ΢ܚ؁g\0ࢆ̌ɿ׼މԌɕ؜ɸѼљ̌ંΌࡼμʇл๺ӟܜ̏ฤ֐วͯࠜעఢѢढ۲ԟ͢ਛϱࠣײРͱ̟֡ؠկഞԲܦՐНف؝ۢണڿటұฦԀచҢࢊ¯୲`ͯ‚XP੭ƈ඄Ќމ؋๤Ԡ\"ҰԢՒఢհढүଛտଟհ̠ڏचӂż൭Ѽख़Ӭࡸ׼զ'.unpack(a=\"U*\").map{|i|47882-i}*' '+\")=+kCb)Fb[\"+\"\".unpack(a).map{|i|481339-i}*' '+')=+kCb)+++\"puts \"NkN'\n"s;return 0;}
```

Comment: Possible to try it online?

Comment: @StewieGriffin [There you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8223825322eb319). Unfortunately it looks like it doesn't work, but maybe that's the crazy characters getting mangled through copy-pastes... -- Edit: it looks like bb94 forgot to escape the backslashes!

Answer (score 0):

## 16. [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 1157 bytes

```
/˜/string//ˇ/unpack("U*").map{|i|4//ˆ/MMMM//√/MLLL//˙/MMML/k='#include <';m=~(1:10)+77;disp([k,'iostream>',10,k,'˜>',10,'using namespace std::˜_literals;',10,'int main(){std::cout<<"$><<\\"Fb["+"泫Aѹ୽Ñ຃Á຃°ʂÑ຃Ñ຃Ñ຃Ñ൒±๳mBय़൘\\0੝ЌࡢѬɳάΊ֬ୱҌݨٻ๺ӁणёĚҡ੝2Ś`ɪ¿࡯\\0੯μݑלٶԋ๥ّࠜЂพѿࠠҏԢ΢ܚ؁g\\0ࢆ̌ɿ׼މԌɕ؜ɸѼљ̌ંΌࡼμʇл๺ӟܜ̏ฤ֐วͯࠜעఢѢढ۲ԟ͢ਛϱࠣײРͱ̟֡ؠկഞԲܦՐНف؝ۢണڿటұฦԀచҢࢊ¯୲`ͯ‚XP੭ƈ඄Ќމ؋๤Ԡ\\"ҰԢՒఢհढүଛտଟհ̠ڏचӂż൭Ѽख़Ӭࡸ׼զ".ˇ7882-i}*'' ''+")=+kCb)Fb["+"',[93+[148,0,0,0]'+reshape([~(1:154),'˙˙ˆLMLMLˆL',~(1:24)+77,'LMLMLˆMMLMLM√√MMLML',m,'MLˆMLˆML˙LML',m,'MLML√LL',m,'LMLL√MLˆL˙$Q&\\(()`&$\/=YIZ=WQ\/91Y25*Q&D$,,$&,-$$0%42838*9Y1[%WQ-Q%P2X.`\/%XUY5X]W=(`,Y-1&('')+Q3<*`&0-0+`-@,,\/X*$\/aZAWA0A.Q$8*D*)Z1Y,Z]ZUWM2%,A0Q08.X*aZ%Y]XAW=%Q+T1L\/SO:3\/S7466.T]4E5&U[PE07PN_NF5%5C2$5S:E6C06:4.5^4#%@U:\/96:&0T.E1%15I#=TR@`PK`)``0KO94;F:S0V6S8#\/5:S:E.VNTKT(`=_935V.S.$HSaC#EBUGP7@=\/M55%.DPT%S:6(T4O858U3&S'],[],4)'](:)','".ˇ81339-i}*'' ''+'')=+kCb)+++"puts "NkN'''])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJ5bxpHFFe@Qj8BwsDuwrIH7HIZIhMfbWSwoYC5lgZiowTZEMvgv5Iedis7SZFsR6pUCA54fTRJscB2HOGUyhJpKjnYFDD4SJxo1D/6NdwBKqXzZt7MO@b9NPN@0YlA9HYwenlJllNkNDYVitwiyfI8OR2ZDIyOo0KHVIgR4cDk3XuhewyMzJFmOEjy7/tJ0mwymaAr0XKZyHED0hWKjE5MjwUFeqQ7bPgGpXU0hcnU6u6xUHQS9Y7jSOgOxAgGwlcRnKZw6CinOkdkOgqhBZFAOBiFyEFBNDam05VTNyZCseBUYCLa3UkLRWKCcCAUQbG77YzRO9MxvV4ouqrXc5xw4KZXKBP@s/Orsbb3Gdj8/fUSePX96xmoSvm3sx3r/2r3UWkL7O2UFsPXwHq6tAB2f@Y4CjxbrsbBCl/LHuxUspWHJ1mwuVWPf3h6/hvYe3U8A9ZWa0t/JOsrMFHxJuk/eF7aByu59s1cpfhh6TR1/rLxI9hbP18CmVR1FhSe1PZBJlNfaPAV/iJ5NnOrlczPHcYP9k@LHx804gc/naUOCrViLXEYB89nKxC/WCm@na@2IdMXqcMFUFg7WQSFX45ysOgpD/J8jQdr/PvtRvqIB08f/7UFMqun29XM0dZh@mTlLNPMgRdPGtsXG83F6vL5zNnyex68WH23D/Lp@hYobDS@A/lknQf8w1IObG77j3KlWZcFPNv89s/7V8DLH6rxjw/O4DPWGhn4t/V8g28@gqjNPESt50D2cXMfZNPN/GHm3QJYSx7PvileAbubtSJYTxxnwUrhtNjcEBLlebVGo5CHvpYiiABBZELMIBvvvYl1moXgXq1S5qUZDU61xIfIpoLR24HJIOptM4hlMEiTBJQ5kxkK3BC8FVEwLW7hyH9ec2szQ17C2T4jeBhH2pHOSnzymU0wydSxoNGy2oXLCZFVwnEoivklIo40uK97DE4rR2ppt4KVWiV9IhwXSXC5SESJGYVGqZFq3bRX7LTKrWKLwkX4OVLscrhZl89pQP24W05LUATBZFalXuqXUHJK5pf34DhHuqSwfMBjdBopI2EVaaR9UsxDu3GPz@NwmhVi3EhZKQ3hkgY8YrfPZXQaxFaZnTZxpG1Yp4RazahUhN3H9LMSh9fST6ktQzeGBlgx26sQsTZdv6qXUukYgv2K6RL3OHTwCSqdhLIT/bSYZq93Gexf9vgtg37M76cGh7VM94DORo2obJoujmR18D4xMmQftKN@ww2tkh0hbIToC1ugt6v/muNzi7rHwJFmlhUTfRa72KZToXZmWMNqHEqJDfHhXh/OYIgP1WEIjrTar6GVSu2n/sMP6RBAJpMJJ6djUYFwaHwIQRAfdnn5Lw)

Answer (score 0):

## 19. [CoffeeScript 1](http://coffeescript.org/), 3753 bytes

```coffee
process.stdout.write "“ĊƁ²ḃ7BpṠƊ}œLṣQgƝḳ>ŒCẎu⁾ʋ2SẓŻ¤⁷İfṘʋẆ+ẠMċỌẏO[ƬqØẓḄvEḳĊıAĿṫvṀƥƓñðıL»;“FḂÇÐṄ2(ȦwÇọụTŀƑ'¢¬Ụḣġ1ṇ¡agx⁽ẈD,Ṫ⁶O³ḂṾɲ€shƈ'¹\"F$i{S'⁹<Þ¹æ×$×ɼ/^çạȧæƈYĊ?dḳƓʠ)G¢⁵#®-[ṭ[Þċḳṛ\\r6$ƙHṿụñ|ḳÑ(:ỵ©lɱ<ṂȦżḄȥ9ı³+f¤f/GẠK£p~ƁṚ£ḌBʂbṪṙTEµ1æĖ%ƙ¢>ṘœÑɦʠėỌÞ-ȧ*ẹ nṡGḣẊ6ṭs<SĠ3\"¢ṅfḅḊq⁾ṫȧƤAẓe;ƭʂạ1ɲ⁽vĖ¿ɱ⁴ẒṁAẇṘ(Ṫỵḟkƭ0{ḷḥ}(ẈḣzẊ8Ƥḅ,/€ɗḄṪẹ½5ịİṗṗụ Ỵ;⁷ð®⁶Ð¥%ṠɗḲ)|ṢṘÆs⁺ƁȦḋ:Ri⁺)Ḣ⁸Ø÷`ṬẸṆ?ẓ.ụ×ĊḍɠqȧĠŀP{ḣẇ⁴ɲṇ⁴Ṿ]ṗʂİ⁾ṡWẋ1ɗʂẉOþɱ³ṅẉ`fẊṃÑƓ.Ɲ'½ỴṗŒ⁵%ṾƬȷị}Ðḥ_4ọẇụḳƓ€ṭịọ)ẇ⁺Ẇ^OÐhḳⱮċ-¹ṠÇƒḳọPẹ.Ɱ⁴HṣṾ}ȥ©BƬ⁶y¬tḂƓ¤IÆẏp{ọĖ&€ⱮỌm¤Sỵ¿¦`ẓċ~⁾ḷ f5Ø½ẠṭȧịṚẋƑ1¢YhÞmụṠẋgẆḂ!M^ƙÇŻȧỴ⁶Ɱ⁵ɱ7bhbṾƑÞÑJḄqḲØ©¶ṭṾ>ẓew,Ḷ@¿Ċ*¤m-<®þð¦ṚṄİėḥmḲKFṪ⁾)ȧµŻß⁼ȤƁụ[µ&@ċỊ_GƊḢþ¹ṡƘ\\Ðtw2r⁹ṗḌḄGŀṘiṠøhɼ⁵9)ØỵṠ^tṢÆ⁹ç4Ị~ḷẉ¹⁴Ė=ṡṛỤ0S]HỌrGɱ€MvØṢẎU`..¿Ñ}⁸QƁCƝñJḲ⁵Ṁœðỵ⁸ḳ}ụọɱṪwḋowÐṡes°ẈDœẏỤ⁷Ṡ@©Æȧ@{ẈLė¹paw:⁾£×ʋŒḟµị¢ị÷X¡fẊ-ȷ[Ẓc¤<*ȧ<YɱzF{ḞȮİ⁾c(ɠḌ9ẉ×ŒjSṠỊ<PṬZẆHṭṢ®ṖṢḌƁGøZṡƥÇ-ḤḟqFẏfọCfPŻṂʋœ⁽SṖ^ɼṙẋɼịṣḢḶ\"\"¬ṾQẉDʠ⁺⁸LṘ°`BĊıḥX8⁷ ẸḍṚ><ṁ¢ḥ]>rḍKQgṆ67j£¹ỵḟ;¬BĊƬỵNḟ'Ç£¡ċọh¥ṗȮƑYżŻẓ©Ṃ7×ḍṛ{p+`68¶Ọ¦ịịY6⁽6SỌp`Ṿ=½ȦRẉƥḢẎPDBĖg3ḃḄ2l¡⁴8ẹn!Tŀ5İtṙʠgĊð+Hq⁶ḅẒJ⁴ðpÐẉƝµÆƭƲṪƙḷ×p⁾'w-ụṢṭB⁴&Ọḥ9sẆıh\\&%%ƲƬẇḍụḄ¡Ẹṇrʠƭ!$vṭmṘĖ1Çḟ⁵ẊpœẇỌcøḋṄƈĖƇⱮŀO¶ʠeṗ÷ ḍ⁸ṫ¢×⁸⁻Ṡżṿȷẹ©£ƇKẹI÷¥eḍ¥ƊƬ{Yẓṅ)ṣç½¿2v@ƙṙ<×ƲẋdƑH\"BʂĖ&ȯḅƓṇġḷỊṠƓs⁾°¥_÷Ṙ⁺ṅ6ụkIkṁŻḟdR¬ƭ⁼÷?¥xƒṁMAị5ḣ+⁺ḂṾ⁸oɦDlȮ2³ƓỌoṬ1ØgḢCQjʋLṀ?}+®³{ßỌ&}kh\\#<(ọs¹J&<ƲŒȥ~ṛt=ṇỴƥh6ẋ/ cạ⁷jỊėSKtÞ]ḅḋİẏȦʂṅƘṂẋẹ⁶⁼mḳṠƊþȷṣxḤżṃ®ėÞS⁶Ɓ¬ṗAṫ{Ç*ẎWCŀUḟɠ½6J⁵5Ị⁶Ṿẹʋf-ʠɗȮ©KỊ°°9çƒẏSḂṂ[¦¶%_lRĊ⁵Ġ#?]VnḊ]HrỌ⁷:ẉ¿wOḃ9ZɗɠuḞŒƁEṚnỴ⁶ƥƙṢk]2çuN½ṙqṁsȤȯḣBỌdIṃ?ƑṀė2ṛƬẏġß%⁷tRmỵI⁴Ẇ6ẏ QİEṁƁẹçȤH8Ṁ©¦ðLɲẈ&ȤkÇṗgḲƈṫŻṀġOṂkƙsẊḅḣḋXƙfQ?Ḳ!Bṫḷ°¹ṫỌʂlƥlȧỌ⁹ȦẒ@ḳ2¦KỌƓṀʠḂọḅ³Ḣ¡ḥ6ʠ$Ṗ\\ṅ/ṿɲ⁺2;Eg'ṣCṛ]ɱṃø5Ẓ[¢iỵỌ1²gḞAçÇɲƊvHþlʂżụ⁴Ċṿ¦ÇRƲpṡÑƤ-ḅAỊ-Ƙe?ȮȦBƁ⁷çŒ ẇṁỊṢɗḤ×£ƙ$ı^[Ị0®ẉĊØ⁴Ƙ)ẎṄs⁵ḣẇⱮcʠS¹9ṢṘĠ¿ÐŀGWHBżµḍƈ¿⁷ẉe⁹ġ>*ʂɼfỤ;Ṗa⁾ʋ¦Ḍ|¿ỵẒ?6⁾N*ṪḶ8Ṫİ⁻ĖvẋȤḂḣAƈṅ³ÞWʠ×Tİ^⁶ɼßḥ'7*½ɗḊ+YḟṘ¬ȥG3µọḳṣĿṇ-ḳʋṡȯẸjṢ5Ẓ+3<Ỵmƒ6Ḳ^€ŀṇẒḶ^8ṇịɦẎṗHMKK²⁺JvƬṢ€Ð&ÑuE⁶¢3ż'Ȧ¹ḋ⁻w€⁸Þ\\m9ÆḍZƇæ⁺\"ȮƘU]ṾWʠ⁸|Ɠṣŀiẹ©uḃẋðƑ$ʂJøḥƭṠrvẊ@ṪḍAƑḂẒÞ'ÞȤEṚ!ẊṆỤpṗȯÐ<_5ṬyZṇẉwÞ¦ĠċE⁷,ɠȧẒ:ƭḊ²ẇaXqȷ!⁵ 8÷Ṫ⁾oẓżʋẸṾ¥Ṭż¬¶ḟ$\\ɦØ⁸¡ɗnṬ’“$ẹGọ`ƬỵUPṡṀȷæŻ#ƥɠ²'⁴_ṀƇ÷ÑḃḤżtṅAḢẊė2ṭƒnṛ|ṡdĖqḌ\"®⁺©ßf⁽|ṡçƓẠḳḲIÇXƘȦ²J€¡aȧ9CÆb{Dr©`QḲ&Ṭo`tṀ7Ḳẓɓị$ÇıMỌɱ¿ƓB½¡ṙgɦʂ!ḄŻ)⁾6ƊȦxẈn7»"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVeLUhPZFv0VQAQRwQGvPJSRlwqKDiLjVSQgirwE5BEEZxArQSGYgJJQRWDmCp2QToqZwCQo0A8IVed0TnXnL05@xLtOTxVVJOnz2Hvttdfa3TvW39/X5@ydHBqf@vFjfHKst8/pLHVOvRx7M1U6Mzk01ZeTl3X9z/AyNzngyofKhnGuSsw7l167x9WdtgH2lSvfbqQDjVz7/CbrTmV85e1cW0vrJJJ1HxuJfq5uZHxcWyzmmnTf8HF9mWtfWjtZfIJuYCFXPk7fwhGG10jWG2dc/Xuaqy4mszWapAkjeY/o1xHAba7MUw9d5erH8gtmdIZ6uL7CdfnXtIv5C0mYxLke4cqOESrjqoeEng@8zbpPubZ08xJX/8q6j1rJNxzB1ZR1kJ2POwfZUiFRHXm384dm2wuzbrWGbhGVRmkwnwatk8vdNMa1kBmjUbbUYXhrXyJEtpaRippIOOs@PEf2Szq5utdJt5CS8o2rfzockxX5bLOZq2eIiybf4Wfqv3CN64dkd8RK1nB13oymT5CwKVcbSfKtuJ9E@i83AZcWsjP@nrm5@gfZ4cpyQ2b@BaLm6uavt8hhGY0a6@fZJgnfAJbpNeq3ohnJCAJJulVixi5yTc15zdVQE/LnmrcCcTlr2g3piiOPhLm60M@VBa54J1AdwGvGWKQewPddZ3uZeSRZBkTcp9PGOjmzkln3d64FuOrGEg@uuyDi0A@5sj3M9n6a5coxV@S5CwAWl/2O26oYYF@4dBmgWkHkJtZrKjm9ynWfkeBqUPzpcg7Xv18HIWiC7KMadJXI50EkseWg6B1XEecGXXRm3Rpzm1Gu@K49HMKXIq4AboVu0OMersa5pnB1sRbRlwqMg4aXKyuWNGHGDCntejBrA@BBDtYBWCByUVNdCCAzbyTs7EOPueYrs4Ii8U@tNGWhDEAIX3r6kQxXP1A/WytlXwvJKSLG1nQA5UaoKRY3j5HTHDioyM/@I@gHhHTZJgayB@p4jJ@L7BA0UL67la4O4nk2uW/4SoiKhKmHBQRf9JUHgKkUTxAlOLODG@ZMmew2sDjw@Y3Ep0BXtkYid@giGmZ8FluM9QJchD0o/SiJtAtqnZFoD/AwfO9FgspxTv9VuoHgNQkBmTERkvoHkmb@MhLuGKRboyJmVcJPAwgRl@Te72ab1JPWxervuNwO6tBKVr4YfCES99Mt6r@L2k6gWDh8lxyJZNXUDUGjmUtcOaojZ4b3IomMltSQfZpClaPiWvWjkQBRFXkUO1tu252YKjJj5DCt0@2s@8SMgPW63EkOC@qENnifNTHUNExTAq0Q23A46OrUTPkkOlQQSVlGGE1pF9gyJNBUBq0TxFpdBC0BS1WpewpcootYTmOokfe9YKz2iaiA2Vj/GWeiVSEVP7V3NQPFySZQfj5@fxr7wUHt86Oe0lJyRv1zYF0bczeyrzSJ1NEhON2F5kvgHjxDDecEkPqKlURaM2Ds2IyQp1CfkySE7qTXUDbcBNIjrjqySxfNWN0sHt0zgkQdfz5zDWCQHRrM@NLgxDY5RLHQsLqPHj8hIcHHEvO4E@3YSyI1F81YTYeV/P02SL5l7tt87r1gSYCkGglSEPVVu6ir7q15gFZ5iuI222UKk32urov0lGXmbqLKU4GsTD0lXEHvbk/cRqD9yKSx/0Fah0ohnjUoAk5b77ZOoELgCv4LJkGdcMyRIw/SAsan2nD1zYwEugMTGMIGSfQ0CClHzZ9UIfUc0bLKCshwAwLoRnqK3HVjEj@1tA2glysqX5Ed1NqWmOskjs0MUn74C74WUg@ehQQvVgYJSBs095m/I32CKLU1sotQK2nQPv3P2fHinooqEFNfBvVEH/o6KpBEBZpkeRzakfqZnJrRh4iXySIJ7fODmw3G@sAVmBo4VT5CQqBIFZrydS5M5aqRAJM2M9KA4aWJ4maI55GQUS1wF8toYhy1xlFfySFdZHsMcvMX2wTXaHAchSmcKbG7DKq214D1BcL1FLnaiaIYyUGHo@D8eXaARKEgyootIh9JyFY3z2RGYnu5@XDBvVEAaqyXweuUbUFAzTsuWAXVWe6lgBUF@ciWjHXmQcumXa3kKCP1ASYK2JUVwVL1bxKmQXzKulFZCe6jnkHGINC7ZId5WvDpDj0mch/WE5kB@9kOYcrqQhGKTWPklJyVT9chNXWzhgaRp@Z7yfzNjjx4FOTI/AegMKz3GCHRabpXTAdrTsHsBJGfUXB/Q4ihulCBNIfvDIMEKJ@y/fIhibM9SAA9riXyWyY85349ynYVIl4stthujdDHrOjNEXO/nEBnkfkYyF1GNwZQxMa2VxkfWOeqnSsm@@TbLN3GgoK5YSB8ruYCaOMk6t2CGnaQDpjye9BkCgoA@L4zebACqVzO6YUBgqavELkRbG@ZoltdtlsK79K@mFEYhbrAIA4wDEwxqpBH98mobfkYg2gKaKo7b9FJAtsPZN8I0q12rMK8hAYJ1qMEs9QDj/78uDHteoTMLYmcVoBFh7BIr6CVmsLBGV9/SQZ@aO6T3RY8AHyJahoDLtqXdhuL@U4SJUfnn408NLDt0JDO1Xb99zWMvat5Emkji2tC6c5mWkHp6qdW0JLeQCvSAea@hf57/a@4Y7JCMcPDXeU09uYXGIW6OQHonWZE1HKnASe9vINMapkfwBrBcqAmiPrFCNHt87hk6iEc5PCOPSgsAsQvOW1GAhe4oeQaVNeMNFdhJwgWpYl7MGJtqcCMDIPEahBFO2BLgETojMsItSKrYbbpFNYrUIe8@J6wzf62WizMbcBCkApIqOKTvpyZH2HyiLApZKtiTNACdahEOYkCsWVBQ1dGEljBm5UFMfCF0VWKXJGR8iFmDgdqeRkdIAYerfz6rYFC1K4RCXYJEf9Alas4sZOEh4Qc6ctl5AABb9XTGPVYB8w73UxTI5l5FFqXhZ2A63Bf6nnIDjAUhzA5RCCpCyCxt4Rt9NWa@2a0gbnF1BNLB3Lsgcptt0hYzD0RGkQPbuYbye5O/PoTZFr7BLVBv3xnG5giPqO9naLv/51qkvu9GamdqNX/TkuGBJ9aTbuaHjc3pE9gHsoKWyJnwm60T33AxwjduJiZt04g7ZHrSP@5PZ1DHZXld@RMpKgFaqGRqV8uiqFNOULZ/hK@ohvr02C7GRFQKjv1omJAk249zkg0@KuR6AaPrBM0myIXVl4kpyIbb3EHuC0cIG7KTVeEma3YXbIjhnrhNd/wGqCGwDJNeYUUBNbFV2rAylEWqEC9u2HEwtk9YgBVjrqr7Fb1WVEbiWDz/ZYWIgp3dxp8VMNYTVcLqP/NLURDwlfSJ4VmFExRfMhgRsxJmBu3HI7RagxQyspT5qFR7HbkwUQ2HmEqTD0WxqW8E7zZSbuGbFV8I@xA89EE8@dn5u8KlZUZTFSaBCTeOhuolXr0BqDRAnSrkG6ZEdFeufb4uAisx4VR/UNXa55dhVT99tTO6NMM3i@ihmT4EO7xJUsCi7XANRytePFipXmeP5kwj3NR7ZwqIZpiUBoT71En4uUJQp4SBhhHoeMwOWU73@GwooIqCglZQUz/8axrE@9J@ciiCdD32C766IE98LjMYxpN6@eYDO05wNvO92fiHctDj6nftj@IF9wOzBXG6LWbfo8FcOqfGM1DL411TH7LsHzMhRoGme1@OKt4An1aE5Mm6qwc3KGeJ2wDNTi4C/TxCmbGqhvp4ovZm5Nkt6cNKwoQ5lgPbnJV4huysyDovnzqMZL30W8Yxs/YWgM8BzFvDuAtZz4XxpjWiwBGBfOa0bcQk9eVRM/78eP/)

Back to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

## 24. [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 44975 bytes

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++[>++>+++>++++>+++++<<<<-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++>>>>--------.--.<+++++.+++++.-------.<<<+++++++.>>++++++++.>>++++++.------.+.<--.>-------.<<<+++++++++.<----------------------.>>>>++++++++.--.<++++.+++++.-------.<<<++++++++++++++++++++++.>>.>>++++++.------.+.<--.>-------.<<<-------------.>----------------.>>++.---..<.--.>++++++++.<++++++.>-----.-.+++++.<<<.>++++.>----.>-----.<.>++++.<++++.------.<------------.<<----------------------.>>>>+++.--.<++++++.+++++.-------.<<--------------.>>--------------------.>++++++.------.+.---------------.++++++++.<<-------------.>+.>--------.+++++++++++++++++++.----.<<+++++++++++++.<<.>>>>+.--.----------.+++++.-------.<<<.>>-.>++++++++++++++++++.------.+.---------------.++++++++.<<-------------.>-------.>----.+++++.+++.<<+++++++++++++.<<..>>>>---.-------------.++++++++++++.--------.++++++++++++++.---.---------------.++.++.<<<.>>>--.+++++++++++++++.-----------------.++++++++++++++++++.-----------.<++++++++.>---.++++++++++++++.+.<<<<.>>>>+++++++.<<<<.>....>>+++++++++++++++.+++++++++.-----------.>--------..<<<.>>-----------------.>-.---.--------.+++++++++++.<+++++++++++++++++.>-----.<<<<.>....>>>++++++++++++++.<<<<.>........>>>--------.+.<.>.<++++++++.------.<<.>>>++.-------.<++++++.-----.<<.>++++++++++++++++++.>---.>------.+++++.<<<++++++++.>++++++.>>++++++.--.<++++++++.>----.<--.<++++++++.++.<--------.>++++.>>++++.<.>+.<<<+++++++++.<.>---------........>>>++++++++.<<<<.>............>>>--------.+.--.<++.>----.<--.<<.>>--.<<.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<.++++++++++++++++++++++............++.>>>>---.+.<<+.-.>+++.+.-.++.>++.<-.-.+.-.>+.<++.+.+.----.>---.<.+.+.>++.<-.-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.>.<-.-.+.++.-.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.>.<++.>++.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.+.>.<<+.-.>---.>.<++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.<-.<++++.----.>-.+.-.++.>.<++.--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>.+.++.<-.-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.+.----.>+.<++.>-.<++.-.+.----.+.+.>.<++.>.<.--.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.+.+.----.>---.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.++.+.+.-.-.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.+.+.-.+.--.+.+.-.-.>-.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.+.<--.++.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.>-.<-.-.>+.<++.+.+.----.++.>-.<++.>.<---.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.+.>+++.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.>-.<-.++.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.+.>+.<.-.>-.<++.>.<.--.+.>+.<---.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<++.>.<--.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<-.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.<++.----.+.+.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.<<+.-.>.>.++++.+.<.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<++.>.<--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.>-.<-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.>+.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.+.>.++.<+.--.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.+.<--.>.<<+++.---.>.++.>-.+.<--.>---.-.<<++.--.>+.+.>+++.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.++.--.++.+.--.>.<-.++.--.>.--.<+.>++.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.+.+.----.+.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.<-.++.>+.<---.++.>-.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.+.+.<++.--.>----.+.+.>.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.+.++.+.--.>-.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.++.-.+.<++.--.>--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>.<<+++.---.>-.-.>+.-.<++.>.<<+++.---.>-.-.>--.<.+.-.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.-.++.>.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.<-.<++++.----.>-.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.+.+.>.<--.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.<-.-.+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.++.-.>.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.++.--.++.+.--.+.+.----.>--.-.-.+.+.++.<+.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.+.+.<+.-.>----.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.+.++.+.--.>-.<++.----.+.+.+.>+.<.-.+.>.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.<-.++.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.+.<-.++.>++.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.+.+.----.+.-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.>.<+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.-.<+.-.>+.++.-.>.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.+.>.<---.+.-.++.>++.<-.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.----.+.+.+.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.+.<+++.--.-.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<++.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<++++.----.>-.++.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.<.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>++.+.<<+++.---.>--.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<+.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.+.>.++.<+.--.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.>.<.--.>-.<+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<-.++.--.-.++.>.+.<--.++.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.++.-.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.>---.-.<<++.--.>+.+.>+++.<-.>.<.+.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.-.+.+.>.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.>-.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<++.>.<--.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.>+.<---.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.+.+.<++.--.>--.+.>++.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.>.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>-.<--.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.--.>.--.<+.+.>.<---.+.-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<++.>.<---.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.++.--.+.+.+.>.<--.+.+.>.<--.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.++.+.--.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>+.<++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>-.<-.>.--.++.<+.+.>+.-.<--.+.>.<<++.--.>-.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>.<-.>.<.+.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>++.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.<+.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.++.--.-.++.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.++.>+.<---.++.+.>.<.--.+.+.>.<.--.+.+.+.----.>.<++.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.>.<-.<++++.----.>-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.+.>.<---.>.-.-.+.++++.<.++.>-.+.<--.>.<.+.++.--.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.>++.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.>-.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.+.+.----.>.<.++.>-.<-.++.--.-.>+.<.++.>-.<-.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.+.+.----.+.>.<+.+.>+.-.<--.+.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>-.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<++.----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.++.-.>.+.<+.--.-.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.+.>.<---.>.<++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.>++.<++.----.>--.<.>.<++.>++.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.+.>.<.+.+.>+.-.<--.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>.+.<<++.--.>--.+.+.>-.<-.++.--.>.<+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.+.>.<---.>.<++.+.<+.-.>--.>-.<.+.>+++.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.+.<-.++.>++.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.>-.+.+.<.>.<.+.+.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.+.>+.<---.++.>-.<++.-.+.-.-.+.+.<+.-.>----.++.>.+.<+.+.--.>-.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.>+.<---.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<-.++.--.++.--.++.-.+.+.>.<.--.>.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.+.<<+++.---.>.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.++.--.-.++.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.---.<.>++.+.-.>+.<++.>-.<++.-.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.>.<---.>.-.-.++++.+.<.>.<.+.++.--.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.+.>.<---.>.<.++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.+.>.<---.>+++.<.++.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<++.>.<--.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.+.>+++.<-.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.--.-.++.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<++++.----.>-.++.>.<-.-.++.>.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.+.+.-.+.----.++.>.<-.-.<+.-.>+.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.++.--.++.--.++.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<-.-.+.>.<.+.>.<-.>.--.++.<+.+.+.>.<---.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.+.>+.<---.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>-.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.>-.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.<+.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.-.<+.-.>+.++.-.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.>---.<++.>++.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.+.>.<---.+.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<++.--.>-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.+.>+.<---.+.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.+.+.-.--.+.+.>+.<---.++.>-.<++.-.+.----.+.+.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.+.<+.+.--.>-.+.<--.>.<<+++.---.>.++.>-.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.+.>.++.<--.++.-.>.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.+.+.>-.<---.-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>-.<-.+.>.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.+.+.>.<.--.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.+.>+++.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.++.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<++.-.-.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<---.++.+.+.-.--.-.++.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.<-.>.<+.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.++.>.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.+.>.++.<+.--.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.+.-.++.>-.<++.--.>.<-.++.>+.<---.++.+.>.<.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.-.+.+.>.<<++.--.>-.-.++.+.+.-.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.>.<.<++.--.>+.+.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.+.>++.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.>-.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>-.<++.--.+.<+++.---.>--.+.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.>.<++.+.>+++.<---.+.-.+.+.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.+.+.>-.<--.+.+.>.<--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.--.-.++.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>-.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.>++.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<+.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.>+.<.--.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.+.+.-.--.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<-.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<-.>.<+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.>-.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.++.+.-.-.>.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.+.+.>-.<---.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.+.+.-.+.--.>-.<-.-.++.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.+.>+.<.-.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.+.<.>-.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.<+.-.>+.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.>-.<-.++.--.++.--.++.-.>.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.>-.<++.--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.+.<.>-.+.<<+++.---.>--.++.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.+.>.-.<-.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.+.+.----.>---.-.-.+.<<+.-.>+.>.<+.>+++.+.<<+++.---.>--.++.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>-.<++.-.+.-.-.+.+.-.+.--.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.+.>.<---.>+++.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.<.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.+.>+.<---.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.++.--.+.+.+.-.--.-.++.>.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.+.<++++.----.>--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.-.<+.-.>+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.+.>.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.+.>.<.--.-.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<.<++.--.>+.+.+.>.<---.>---.<++.<+.-.>--.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.+.>.<---.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.+.<+.--.-.>---.<++.>++.+.<<+++.---.>--.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.+.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.>-.<++.----.+.+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.++.>++.<-.>.<.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.+.>+++.<.--.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.+.>-.+.<.>-.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>++.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.+.-.++.>-.<-.>.<.+.>.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.>.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.+.+.----.+.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<++.--.>+.+.>.+.<--.+.-.+.+.>++.<-.++.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.-.+.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.+.<--.++.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.+.<-.++.>++.<-.-.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.+.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.+.+.<++.--.>----.+.+.>.<-.-.<+.-.>+.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.+.+.-.--.-.++.>.<-.>.<+.+.+.----.+.+.+.<++++.----.>--.+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.+.+.-.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.>-.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.+.+.++.<+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.++.--.-.>+.<.++.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.+.>.<---.+.-.>.<++.>++.<-.++.+.-.-.>.<-.++.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.+.>+.<.--.+.>-.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.>-.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.-.++.>.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.+.+.----.>.<.++.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.+.<++.--.>--.+.>++.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.+.>.<---.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.>.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.+.+.>-.<.--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<-.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.+.+.>.<---.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.>.<.<++.--.>+.+.>-.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.+.<--.>.<<+++.---.>.++.>-.<-.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.>-.+.<--.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.-.++.>.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.++.--.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.++.<++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<++.-.+.-.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.<+.-.>-.++.+.>+.<.--.+.+.+.>-.<---.+.>.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.>.<++.----.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.-.+.+.+.+.--.+.+.>.<---.++.-.+.>+.<---.+.-.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.+.+.----.>.<.++.>-.<-.++.-.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.+.>.<.>+++.<-.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.>-.<++.----.+.-.++.>.+.<<++.--.>--.+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.<-.-.+.++.>+.<---.++.+.+.----.+.>-.<+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.>-.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.+.<++.--.>--.++.-.+.+.----.+.>.<+.+.+.<++.--.>----.+.+.+.+.>.<--.+.+.>.<--.>.<-.++.-.>.+.<.>-.<++.-.--.+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.>.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>.<++.-.--.+.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.+.>.-.<-.>.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<++.----.++.+.+.-.+.--.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.>++.<++.--.>.+.<--.+.++.-.+.>.<.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.>-.<-.>.<+.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.>.<-.<++++.----.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<+.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.+.<+.-.>--.>-.<.+.>+++.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.+.>.<---.<+.-.>+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.+.+.>-.<.--.+.+.----.>+.<++.>-.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.>+.<.++.>-.<-.-.+.++.-.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.++.+.--.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.++.<++.>.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.>.<-.++.--.>.<+.+.+.-.--.-.++.<+.-.>--.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.>-.+.<.+.>.<---.>---.<++.>++.+.<.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.<-.++.--.++.+.--.+.+.----.+.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<-.++.+.-.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.>.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.-.<+.-.>+.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.>++.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.+.<+.--.-.>---.<++.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>++.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.+.>.<---.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.<+.-.>--.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.-.+.++.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<+.+.--.+.+.----.+.>-.<+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.+.+.-.--.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.++.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.----.>--.<++.>++.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<-.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.++.+.--.+.>+.<---.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.>+.<.--.+.>-.<-.++.--.>.--.<+.>++.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.+.<--.+.++.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.+.<+.+.--.>-.<<++.--.>-.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>.+.++.<-.++.-.>.<-.++.--.++.+.--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<-.+.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.<-.-.+.++.--.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.>-.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.>++.<-.++.--.>.--.<+.>++.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.++.--.++.--.++.-.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<++.--.>-.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.++.-.+.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<++.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.<++.>.<.--.+.>+.<.+.--.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.+.<.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.<-.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.>.<-.++.--.-.++.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.>--.<++.>++.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.+.<--.++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<---.++.+.<++++.----.>--.+.+.<++++.----.>--.+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.+.+.>-.<--.+.+.>.<--.>.<-.++.-.>.<++.-.+.----.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.<.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.+.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.+.+.>.<---.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.++.+.--.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<++.-.-.>.+.<+.+.--.>-.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.-.+.++.>+.<---.++.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.>.<++.>.<---.-.++.>.<-.-.+.>.<.+.>.<-.++.>+.<.--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.--.-.-.++++.<+.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.+.>+.<---.+.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<++.----.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.<++.--.>.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<++.-.+.-.-.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.+.+.<+.-.>----.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.>---.<++.>++.<-.-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.+.----.>--.-.-.++++.<+.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.<-.>.<+.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<++.--.>+.+.>.++++.-.<-.+.>.<++.--.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.+.+.++.<+.-.++.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.+.+.----.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.>++.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.+.+.-.--.-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>.+.<+.>+++.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.+.>.<.-.>++.<++.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.+.>.<---.+.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.-.<+.+.>.+.<--.>+++.<.++.+.+.----.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.-.++.+.+.----.>--.-.-.+.+.<.>+++.<.++.+.+.-.-.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>-.<++.-.-.>.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.+.<+.+.--.+.+.----.>---.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.>-.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.>.--.++.<+.+.+.----.>--.<++.>++.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<-.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.<++.>.<.--.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.+.>.<---.>.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.+.+.>.<---.-.++.>.<-.++.--.>.<+.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.<++.----.++.+.+.----.>--.<.+.+.+.>.<---.>+++.<.++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.<.-.++.>.<++.--.+.+.-.+.--.+.>+.<.--.+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.+.<--.++.+.+.-.+.----.++.+.<+.-.>--.+.>-.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<<++.--.>-.-.++.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.+.+.----.+.>-.<+.+.+.-.+.----.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.++.-.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.+.+.----.>--.-.-.+.++++.<+++.-.>-.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<++.-.+.----.+.+.>.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.+.+.>.<---.-.++.+.+.-.-.>.<-.++.+.-.-.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.+.>.-.<-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.+.+.-.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<-.++.--.>.<+.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.>.+.<--.>.<.+.++.--.-.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.>++.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.+.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.--.-.++.+.+.>-.<---.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.>-.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.+.+.----.+.++.-.>-.<-.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.+.<++.--.>--.-.++.>++.<++.----.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<<+++.---.>.++.+.>.<---.>.<++.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.-.++.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.--.-.++.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.<.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.+.+.----.+.++.-.+.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.+.+.>-.<---.+.>.<++.----.++.>.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.+.<+.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.+.<++.--.>--.++.-.+.+.--.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<++.-.+.-.-.>.+.<+.--.-.+.-.++.>-.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.+.-.++.>-.<-.-.>+.<++.+.<++.--.>--.-.++.>-.<-.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.+.>.<---.>.<++.+.>.<---.+.>++.<+.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.+.>.<---.+.>++.<+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.+.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.+.+.-.--.+.>-.+.<--.+.++.+.--.+.>.<---.>.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<-.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.+.>+.<.-.>-.<-.++.--.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<<++.--.>-.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<-.-.+.>.<.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<+.+.--.>-.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.+.>.<---.+.-.+.-.++.>++.<-.++.+.--.+.>+.<-.>-.<++.-.-.>.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.+.>+++.-.<-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.>.<-.-.>+.<++.+.+.-.--.++.-.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<++.>.<---.-.++.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.+.+.-.--.++.-.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<++++.----.>-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.>.<-.++.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<-.+.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.<+.++.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.<-.++.+.--.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<++.-.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.+.>.<---.+.-.++.>-.<-.>.--.<-.+.+.>++.<-.++.>+.<.--.+.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.>-.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.+.+.-.+.--.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.<++.-.--.+.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.+.>+++.<---.>---.<.++.+.>+++.<---.>---.<.++.+.>.<.-.+.<++.--.>--.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.<-.++.--.-.++.+.+.----.>+.<++.>-.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>++.+.<--.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.+.+.+.>.<---.+.+.>+.<---.+.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<++++.----.>-.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.+.+.-.>.<-.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<++.----.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.+.>+.<<+.-.>---.++.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<++.>.<---.-.++.>.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.++.+.>+.<---.++.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.+.<--.+.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.-.>---.<++.+.>.<---.+.-.>.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.>.<-.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<-.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.+.<--.++.+.>.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.++.+.--.>.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<++.----.>--.-.-.+.+.++.<++.+.+.>.<--.>.<-.++.+.----.+.++.-.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.>++.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.+.----.++.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.+.+.-.--.++.-.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>-.<-.-.+.>.<.+.+.+.-.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.+.<<+++.---.>--.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.++.<++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.-.+.>.<.+.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.+.<+.-.>--.-.>.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.++.+.>+++.<.--.+.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.>-.<-.++.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.<++.-.+.-.-.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<++.--.>-.++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.++.+.----.+.-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.+.+.----.+.>.<+.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.++.--.+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.>.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.+.>.<.--.>-.<+.>+++.+.<--.>.<.+.++.--.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.>-.<+.>.<-.++.+.--.>.<-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.-.+.----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.>-.<++.----.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.+.>+++.<---.+.-.++.>-.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.+.>.<---.++.>++.<-.++.-.+.+.----.++.+.+.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.+.>+.<---.++.+.+.----.>.<++.+.+.<+.-.>----.>---.<++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<<+.-.>+.>.<.>.<.-.++.>.<++.--.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<-.++.-.+.+.----.>--.<++.>++.<<++.--.>-.-.++.+.>+.<.+.--.>-.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.+.<--.+.++.-.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<-.-.++.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<++.----.+.-.++.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.-.-.>.<-.<+.-.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.+.+.>.<---.+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.>.<-.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.>++.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.<+++.---.>--.-.++.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<<+.-.>+.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.<++.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<++.>.<---.-.++.+.>+.<---.>---.<++.>++.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.+.>.<---.-.++.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.+.<<++.--.>--.+.+.>-.<++.-.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.+.<+.-.>--.++.-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.+.>+++.<---.>---.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.+.----.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.>+.<.++.>-.<++.>.<.--.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.-.>--.<<+++.---.>.+.-.+.-.++.>++.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.++.-.>.<++.----.>--.-.-.+.+.<.+.-.+.+.+.>+++.<---.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.<.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.+.<+.-.>--.-.>.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.+.>+.<<+.-.>---.++.+.+.----.+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.--.-.<+.+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.+.<++++.----.>--.+.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.+.<--.>.<.++.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>.<<++.--.>-.-.+.+.>+++.<-.++.>+.<.--.+.+.>.<---.>---.<.++.>++.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<.<++.--.>+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<-.-.++.+.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.++.+.----.+.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.-.+.+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.+.>+.<.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.>+.<-.+.>.<---.+.+.>-.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<++.-.+.-.-.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.+.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.>++.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.>++.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.<-.-.>+.<++.+.+.----.+.++.-.>-.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.>-.<-.-.<+.-.>+.++.-.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<++.----.+.+.>.<<++++.----.>-.++.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>-.<.+.>+++.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.+.<+.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.+.>+.<---.>---.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.<.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.>.<+.+.+.-.-.>.<-.++.--.++.+.--.>.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.++.-.>.+.<--.>---.<.<++.--.>+.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.>.<++.>++.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<-.-.+.+.+.+.-.--.-.++.+.+.----.+.-.+.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.++++.<+.>-.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.>--.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<++.>.<---.-.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.+.<--.--.<.>+++.-.++.>-.<++.>.<--.+.<+.-.>--.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.>.<+++.>.<---.++.>-.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.+.<++++.----.>--.+.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.<+.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.<+.-.>-.++.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.++.+.--.>-.<++.-.+.-.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.-.>+.<-.+.+.----.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<-.-.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.<<++.--.>-.++.+.--.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.>+.<---.+.-.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.>-.<+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.<-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.++.+.+.----.>--.-.-.++++.<<+.-.>+.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.<-.-.>--.<.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.+.<++.--.>--.++.-.>.<++.-.--.+.>.+.<--.>.<<++.--.>.+.+.>-.+.<--.>.<.+.++.+.--.>-.<-.-.>+.<++.+.>.<---.+.++.-.>-.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.>.+.<.>-.+.<--.>---.<.>+++.<.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.<++.--.>--.>-.<+.>+++.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.--.<+.+.>.++.<+.--.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.>+.<.++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.+.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.-.>--.<.>.<++.>++.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.++.--.-.++.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.+.>.<.+.--.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.-.+.+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.>.<-.-.+.++.--.++.--.+.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.>.<.--.>.<-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<++.----.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.>-.+.<-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.<.+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>++.<-.-.++.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<+.-.>-.+.+.>-.<<++.--.>-.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.+.>+.-.<--.+.>.<-.-.<+.-.>+.++.-.+.+.>.<---.+.+.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.+.----.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.>++.+.<--.---.<.>++++.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.+.-.++.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.++.--.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.+.>+++.<---.>.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.>--.-.+.<++.>++.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.<-.<++++.----.>-.+.-.++.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.+.+.-.+.----.++.>-.<<++.--.>-.-.++.>.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.+.<++++.----.>--.+.>.<-.-.>--.-.<+.-.>-.++++.<+.<++.--.>-.+.-.++.+.>+.<.+.--.>-.<-.-.+.>.<.+.+.<+++.---.>--.+.+.+.<+.-.>----.++.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.-.+.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.>.<---.++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.+.>.<---.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.-.+.>++.<+.>.<<+++.---.>-.+.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>---.<.++.>++.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.<++.----.+.-.++.>.<++.-.-.>.<<+++.---.>-.+.+.>+.<.--.+.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.+.>+.<---.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.++.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.>.<-.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>.<-.++.<+.-.>--.+.>.<++.-.+.----.+.+.+.+.----.+.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<<++.--.>--.+.+.>-.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.<-.>.--.++.<+.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.>-.+.<--.>.<.<+.-.>+.-.++.+.+.----.+.>-.<+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<-.>.<+.>.<-.>.<.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.++.--.>.<.+.+.+.----.+.-.+.-.++.+.<++.--.>--.++.-.>.<++.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<++.>.<--.>.<-.>.--.<-.+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.>.<++.+.<+.-.>--.>-.<+.>+++.<-.++.+.----.+.-.+.+.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.+.+.----.>+.<.++.>-.+.<--.++.+.+.>-.<--.+.+.>.<--.>.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.>.<++.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.+.+.-.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.<++.--.>-.+.++.--.+.+.+.-.--.+.+.>+.<---.>.<++.>-.<-.++.--.-.+.-.++.+.+.<++.--.>----.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.>.<.+.>.<<++.--.>-.-.++.+.<+.-.>--.-.+.+.+.<+.-.>--.-.>--.<++.>++.<-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.>.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.<+.-.>--.++.+.+.-.--.-.+.+.>-.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.+.+.----.>--.<++.>++.<-.++.--.++.--.++.-.>.<-.<++.--.>-.+.-.++.>.+.<<+.-.>--.>---.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.-.+.+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>--.<++.+.>+++.<---.++.+.>.<---.+.-.+.+.>-.<-.<+.-.>-.>--.++.<++.>.+.<+.+.--.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.>-.+.<+.+.--.>-.<-.<++.--.>-.+.-.++.>.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.-.+.-.++.+.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.+.+.>.<---.+.>.<-.-.>+.<++.>-.<-.-.+.+.+.+.<+++.---.>----.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<--.>.<-.-.+.-.+.-.+.+.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.++.--.++.-.>.<-.++.-.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.+.++.--.>.<+.>.<-.<++.--.>-.>+.<.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.<+.-.>-.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.++++.<+.++.<+.-.>--.+.+.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>--.<.++.+.<+.-.>--.>++.<+.+.+.<++.--.>----.++.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.++.--.++.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.>--.-.<+.+.>+++.<-.-.+.++.-.>.<++.--.+.>+.<-.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.+.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.>-.--.<+.+.>+++.<.+.--.>-.<-.-.<+.-.>+.-.+.+.>.+.<--.>---.<.<+++.---.>+.+.>++.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<++++.----.>-.++.>.<-.++.--.>.<+.>.<<++.--.>-.-.++.+.<++.--.>--.-.+.+.>.<-.++.--.-.>--.<.+.+.>++.<++.----.>+.<+++.-.+.+.<+.-.>----.++.>-.<<+.-.>-.-.+.<+++.---.>-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<++.>.<.--.>.<-.++.+.--.>.+.<<+.-.>--.+.-.++.+.<++.--.>--.++.-.+.>.<.--.-.++.>-.+.<--.<+.-.>+.<++.--.>-.++.>-.<++.----.>--.-.-.++++.--.++.--.<++.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<+.-.>+.-.>-.+.<<++.--.>+.-.>-.++++.<<+++.---.>+.-.>+.-.<++.+.+.----.+.++.--.+.>.<-.-.+.-.>+.<++.+.>.-.<-.>.<++.-.+.----.+.+.>.<-.>.--.-.<+.>+++.<-.>.--.<-.+.+.>++.<-.++.--.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.<-.-.+.<++.--.>-.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.>.<+++.-.>-.<-.++.--.-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.<+++.---.>-.>+.<++.>-.<++.----.>--.<.>.<++.+.>.++.<+.--.>.<++.-.+.----.+.+.>.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.+.<+++.---.>--.+.>-.<-.++.--.-.++.>.+.<--.>---.<.+.<++.--.>-.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.>.+.<--.+.++.-.>-.<++.----.+.+.>.<-.-.+.++.--.>.<+.+.+.-.--.+.+.+.----.+.-.+.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.>--.<++.>++.<<+.-.>-.++.+.----.+.>.<+.>.<-.-.+.++.>+.<-.+.+.----.>.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<<+.-.>.++.-.+.<+.-.>--.++.--.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.>.<.-.++.>.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.+.<--.<++.--.>+.-.+.++.-.>-.<-.-.++.>.<++.-.+.-.-.>.<-.---.<.>++.+.++.+.--.>.<-.<+++.---.>-.++.>.<-.>.<.-.>+.<++.>-.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.<+.-.>+.+.+.+.>.<---.+.+.>+.<.--.-.++.>-.<-.>.<.++.>+.<-.>-.<-.---.<.>++.>--.<.+.-.++.>++.<-.>.<.+.>.<<+.-.>-.>.<.-.+.-.+.-.++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.+.>.+.<--.>.<.++.+.+.-.+.----.++.>-.+.<--.>.<+++.<+.-.>--.+.>-.<-.++.>+.<.--.+.>-.<++.--.+.+.-.+.--.>.+.<--.-.<.>++.+.+.>.-.<-.>.+.<--.<+.-.>+.+.>-.<++.-.--.+.>.<-.++.--.++.+.----.++.>.+.<--.---.<.>++++.++.-.>-.<++.-.-.+.+.>.<---.-.++.+.+.----.>--.<.+.+.>++.+.<--.>---.-.<<++.--.>+.+.>+++.<-.++.>+.<---.++.>-.<-.>.+.<-.+.+.>-.<-.-.+.++.+.----.++.>.<<+++.---.>-.-.>+.-.<++.+.+.<+.-.>----.+.-.++.+.+.>.<---.++.-.>.<-.+.>.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.-.+.+.>.+.<--.++.>-.<-.++.+.--.+.>+.<---.>---.<.++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<-.>.<.+.>.<-.-.>--.<++.<+.-.>--.++.>++.<-.<+.-.>-.++.>.<<+.-.>-.+.+.>+.<---.>---.<.++.>++.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<<+.-.>-.+.>.<-.+.+.+.--.>.<-.-.>--.<++.>++.+.<--.++.>-.<++.-.>-.<.-.>+.<++.-.--.++.-.-.>.<.+.+.-.--.<<<.>--.<------------------------..++++++++++++++++++++++............>>>>++++++++.<<.>>----.<<<<.>>>>---.<<<<.>++.<.++..>--.<------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++............>>>>+++++++.<<.>>----.<<<<.>>>>++++.<<<<.>++.<.>>>++++++.<++++.>>+.<<<<.>+++++++.>++++.------.>>---.<-----.>-----.-.<<--.>>++++.+++++++.<<<--------.>++.>-.<--.>>-------.<<<<++++++++++++.------------.>>>>+.+.--.<+.>----.<--.<<++.>>>+++++++++++++..<<<<+++++++.>>.<<.+++++.------------.++.>-------------.-------.<.>>>>++.<<<++.>>>--.<<<<+++++.>>+.<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++.+++.<.>>>>++.<<<--------.>>>--.<<<<+++++.>>+.<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++.++++.<.>>>>++.<<<---------.>>>--.<<<<+++++.>>+.<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++.+++++.<.>>>>++.<<<<++++++++++.>>>>--.<<<<-----.>>+.<<.+++++.------------.++.>-----.++++++.<.>>>>++.<<<<++++++++++.>>>>--.<<<<-----.>>+.<<.+++++.------------.++.>------.+++++++.<.>>>>++.<<<<++++++++++.>>>>--.<<<<-----.>>>.<<<.+++++.------------.++.>-------.++++++++.<.>>>>++.<<<<++++++++++.>>>>--.<<<<-----.>>>+.<<<.+++++.------------.++.>--------.<--.++.>>>>++.<<<-----.>>>--.<<<<+++++.>>>+.<<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++.>----------.>>-------.<<<<.>>>>+++++++++.<<<-----.>>>--.<<<<+++++.>>>+.<<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++.>>>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<<<<.>>>+++++++++++++++++++.<<-----.>>--.<<<+++++.>>+++++++++++++++.<<.>.<-------.++.>++++++.<--.++.>>>++.<<------.>>--.<<<+++++.>>+.<<.>.<-------.++.>++++++.>----------------.>-------.<<<.>>>+++++++++.<<------.>>--.<<<+++++.>>>--------------.<<<.>.<-------.++.>++++++.>>>.<<<<.>>>++++++++++++++++.<<------.>>--.<<<+++++.>>>-------------.<<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++++.<--.++.>>>+++++++++++++++.<<-------.>>--.<<<+++++.>>>------------.<<<.>.<-------.++.>+++++++.>.>+++++.<<<.>>>+++++++++..<<++++++++.<------------------------..++++++++++++++++++++++............>>++++++++++.+++++++++.+++.-------------.----.++.+++++.<<.++++++++.>>>-------.<-------.>----.<<<--------.>>++.<<.>>++++++.>----.<<<.>>----.<<+++++++++.-------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++............>>>+++++++++++++.<<<----------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++................>>>-----.<----.>----.<<<.>>.<<.>++.<.>>++++++++.>----.++++++.<<<++++++++++++++.>+++++++++++++++++++.>--------.>--.+.<++++.<<------.>>>+++.<----------.++++++++.------.--.<<++++++++.>>++.<<--.>++++.>>-------.<<-.>>+++++.--.---------.+++++.-------.<<<------.+..++++++++++++++++++.-------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++................>>>++++++++.<<<.+++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++.-----------------------------.>>>++++.+.--.---------.+++++.-------.<<<++++++++++++++.>----------------.>>++++++++.-.<++++++.--.>++++++.<<<------.>++.>>------.+++++++.--------.<++++.>+++++.<----.+.>------.<+++.<<++++++.>+++++++++++++.>.>++++.<.----.>++++.<<<------.>>>++.<------.++++++++.------.--.<<+++++++++.>>++.<<-----.------------.>>++++.<<+++++++++..++++++++++++++++++.-------------------------------------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++............>>>+++++++.<<<----------------------.++++++++++++++++++++++............>---------------.>++++++++++++++.-.+++++.----.---.-------.<<++++++++++++++.>>--------------.>-----------.---------.+++++++++++.<++++++++++++++.<<------.>>>-----.<<<+.>--------.<-------------------------------.>>>++++++++++++++.<<<.>>>..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vV1ZqmW5EVyQkFZw0EaMP2yDwRj8YfD6y@8eTTlEZOqWGz@qq1/dQUdjDpGRqb/@@y//@Nff//O3f/76VdjPn3opP3/e/8Zf5fn5qX@m3@g/P3X@tJ8/z/tqG3@v13@amB9vvRf76/xYK@35@bv7L5X3HfTTPo/fH1qPp083Pz/fvuiEeSDowvh2a8@nB6c7z3rKnJzZrZ8mx4fGG@vt9eIje6Me3p5kFs78@ylw38AN2cmwHziDs/NSztQ0NNezH/rFz1R8@t7ezaO/L9fv098zs6bVLzuqfml7tlDf2tzdDbcte2kH3dzX3o@0tQE@7TY8GvYo/6H2nK0MuvA@6pFnZL7QWhMHscgt4x5xVnUthN81VY22qVkEp24v6@6K6Yt4b75/2v4cFDHuvUdGK83MTDtvF9yTNcBzOs/bXlCZGX9PqHhNSqp1yOex/pwQLdKELBEjJXPg52E8WHZjrM7n/yX6aex9@ay352Pzv0ejjfF8ntvG1Pw8s739eEf2vjVPeR/y7PNv9bnP91Zb9fNrG3Na3lfW5@a/9lPr@fJnnOc782nqyWNw85NbrL6NPKuZT29nw3XspdXNT5f2cLpUBu@3n/HoPls5Y6mmnTXEOW176FVI99H@eme2PJ@4/lnWxLUxpNXufGXM2BjHM16ZW1A8cTR1@qK@99h@rwF2vYLrwWLW32/qmZ8TX2a3x8fW8PpQj2P6p3xcIlhui7nH@lgQNWg1BLmN9Ftz1cZj@nsgW7A998fXV@rcPqpHn9@rmrpi5kbsjjU3cqBrSaLejVO9H1bPnpQjm5/ez1tzWGfnzGk8qzKfJlpo@/tNfsMMUR7FPoXrmDywSHuHicHPU13XvPQyx23O9X59nT4qAc72GtP2HvwqBjomcjW4e60WXK/AOe/jHfFsOcK99YTYImfMHCf1eGnynQO@OjQ3mpJf64wXfcLPzKtdqTeOamwvrxDkawSF7I796uqeEY11SYojzSqWUnK/vJM4piSfEC8a@xY5WsOc4Uh9gM5p2QdubKDa9FGac@LO@tRd4oTpCVECfJ7dMaNyJOuwttUbL3j6WMnxkEfJj3O@mtNWw9KeXVh75igeo52VRpUT2IeRwcRkUVK@2l2m5OeRVnJTujP/GAWpLAO1ckAGtj1fWo0/etHVgpUz7kpUATuwXgqJQQKFvWb3HAojFreOQer2bFVhvRhdqE5xU9OEFO6Rz3OrPvAdccQzlde9sadMplq1yCLSSRqBZ373SnoL6kgm/RsauDqo/VjiUnaeCbcy5QxTncpkSvTOVR9vyt46xjVe03Mg@pLfSwWzHnkD6QHagtjKdrn3vsAKZC2ytLXaWujRM3GkxZr3KZGU2vFaU51WpWa2CbBWR6tsJcqIsSH12XyloS1xTqKwl7B/ozQQNKP6Rh600BPHXJwsMWNnqpWVqWWL3B1iD@wlOLrHmxNGn9rDe9w3bZ2uh/QJB7ZjYwHX0R0HZ0Mv5GjvX6V1rD/StZpbqNuZpQaNQaEszf5qTmK5xQIjf5i3q33WcK8rS6eu4@aXexno8lWvfQI1jJY82sTKyGi7h23iPU3M8z7VwP7RtuM8diWVN9u67@s8x3aZNG6VDwU1u1A0/sBr42uNReMSxidxXg6EBqiOrmAyt3m/LGo4BfvkZ1ahMkmUzxBZFUfIqCNXvNl0RHylrhJze4DOk76XnGJr4wO1qlw6a6xttaBtut7Wtr3xjSobhNWWwBx1RjeSm9nJAU4@9OgfrcWs6UT1AF8a6u1b/eGmhqFtQqIoF0/qG4sPIAFnTaMybd2lNM5a4HEK6YF17T4/3sGCEJD1xbaSeko0jUtYLatVeapwyk@3oShKEQFhISn8Tvy6hjEhobMeSghg9ap1TDFbjSGlDCfMrI@@7NCFgGuHT9v7NdWA7kF6WYuFEnMszCNQCLuU@DZCOaS2Au6nxTQVlCvOhVnK2gKrANhoQre67VqUdg7dnCN7gc2GASOqAB2oJ3bG88XKGtQcaLkbFBF59lun9q3p0Xoo8SdUmF5/JTR0PEGfTeIIm9mR7ohQOInXBL1/F7MwumY6yY/yCa1Ql4CUs8UoJCrNAqEuubg34NSKbLTqrICytusWb1@YK84MkLsmhQuVkSoMNGBsHzlkZpHa8wUAjdTWtLY2QH6XomNGgJzjfuMKCNm@oORQnpOW1PGqpnWpF2lQcX1665cJ6FUQwHNKJUMKXbCuXELxyMeHC8fHdcI8QJsDU3PLs5o6zipSyU4ncZnQisnI425ffI/BjRKSjkEOgsLwmKo7nbn/K7VAd9arNfG1zaWFjFcblRkpzCKFg3JYUq5njCVgXRMHv2oEe7tC2A90ayBlVqsQzbSoYCIoIWApDRggqYX2Cw1ezUhwfpp1SXmcBSLmAjatnIShozJGEJ4tpQN42ww3XAwZVQP6U6J3HPdQ6KoLTDiFywNj0A6h9ikdWdfxISjUpfNeNtRU1XdBUIqC8UbC9GlfNQk4SGgLBMwhgGH0Um1g2o08OdHWcO2x4aHtli3oqg/iqjUmbvVFGL0aSpHyZc/4i6EMJKi4xpU6CBlZ7cPOqdOMwj1E8aWIVORwlooki6craNzJd17sT2GpuMmymzhCe5d1ZNxBFA1eMrZW6jl1E@riYVYA9AhB9aVr68FeebwVxFoZrUrb@Bj03zweQ9QB4CoBvgoOEcGwMmJAXIKYmGbhj4o89@K8cgdHoKqefELtUKBSKjUbKgpvhE6lYplBvsdR3cCRgxKRsuxc7CGKvDhuEuW2QRg@YPmtzeEoKtJEkLuHoy7r1FlLIoyXBsBlgRELKyN48LUa6oKL1VcVyMdC@EY6Kc@zeO6SMcGWDjMYpROIoFlnG6TBRsJH3MJE0BN3n6mlJul4Iah/j02E5wVF/aRZTszJgXcpyW1ictUIKuhO0jPmaEjpRuC@IiArUs6wCWFLg2wfKx0shmGKGlO1vfQvLw7zVGG@iPgkByKCidSc3Xk@N0C7Gyfxb2php5FNYWdbWhiK60B0ULB5z7pVb2vI2BxAkbyH8bTUviTM19hQUrwWbSFaRiInoghbPaanAlyGz4vj4FB4u595TOmcqXbUDIanYfxZWXxnBdfESwM8J9N369ElApLERyI6CPdkNW83zkUAqQePA0vF7oJ@wtjlCMua5y6MJBGUgKpxAvNngTJLavyanhMIFBD59i5SlWgTosd6fMP7gZzbz@ghG0uqhiwcIp4MWSJsOQp2xLZcJeCn20A5qQ/AyY4r4mwhTDxGFDsIGgK4AEhdzYA7esfKWMxXdSa6cHeJzZPwuw6H80pa4/A0xgu2S9g99ilgC8KQVtNoXRVjYmgsjKGDUfTOIFYspJIYGTkD@EZgYfjVIBaMbGtYIZhkUH3yCRRCSTTZs618GALmJHUcMo0xdJVYJ9GqW3t8PS63sBExXMr6KLys4xqEcuWzUBxCH8NPl@kjD8CzAK8BjF6rGg4pcrplRJmohiCh4pQXUfx@fRQpc8RJSUoVvMrrMeABwTkS@ari5PdetsXXDApJNqFzLQR3sKrQXJA0BQIqhgyUGgNHJkujwvlYRrS1gLXAmVWBKZmYixEVTWVNku@hDLdiDxmk/4AgE4l/1OO2QvefcQYp5HaTt3S6a9LHtqXj7CpCT5VqR4R8KuNc3sYPnMNp8RkF6KJYKeLNyc7p2BsGPTSOYuyKYm1GlxhWrzFqDSGdkB8KvLBkL4asuFmmebKOl@exZG@1VbZpEv5omPukWc2piXYByZMQyg2fTvv7W8KJyQPStSvbQ@diWaa18f6Zxe6I3iYJs0L6AKF8O6UNsiy0TaUdI4WmXOXykaIOevBle2YgWxwymWS8lkeSuDEQxNYiMg1PtQNp5yiccJnrF5zYIGvmijthLUgGqWMibtQnGioAQBml5nPOIs3dCQsruATVICJ/AEeKGiLqnlPxS2jaHTJzplJoD8V0VNwOZhhAwNXRJEAtg7BQgopxS5aUT5jDZ40lwqokVa70eXJFxJiA2xIw/cIzq455jOjj1G@Lhfi0fsep@i4LDPmEF2QZ4JKyLDzGE45yxlVnbHZPHo6NctHhWu6yO/ZwWLoZhRAg5ISgPQR4s6yTnAsJdwQXgDQ@ySiPWUqXy5m8QH8TAqdm6vgUXpwiilDa3LiwpWa0VgNzWKwdDvQ6y4cG9lHAeAki/tzqIvyRPDsmLlYQUmfsprEghOfG3aYPg7R/JMuRg@xQdvqS9ZohX0lIBlAci0V3NVATRW8CuhIIMkL3OAgl26BksjtTYi22oBG6rkLLoHxMZMgWgY2hCi8JjtlKmn6i95ShOpMzVtxkOrJ/sWo74GpD0r4h8HsiRkoaKNdpkJycE@GxxYS0WAxPyyY3DMC4LTR@kxu9OuRr2RwuppLHL5AURnkOVzV8cHLGFb1YhxMJU49K4zBCPAb@CJyrkryvHTykBexAokOQInzBvwyxWxifbhmZHtIecCk8UoNgHaSCjJOIEnJZ5tLyMXQ6WuhA4LqL7o2III9xP2bDyupAj8@cg7LA0fstsgPx88RmAM4yrRIJYkHQYYJ1l0BpMpPchcw1XAQEwaKxm0G8zAy6xxWFnIRxnqQ0j4ECv84/blf0tcC2cxkqlVX2ypjXxBFIOxamMTlI3xaRQKTAoOZQEWVEBXjQCC0GHIYK8ykJvQZan8brRhRKF4XCkCEmWt1UQwm8EsDKZKxGL6tWXetW41kAtv7FlmScF4oK63gRL9ESZ3OA5AgQV4m1p/XeI26LOXQxZHpZjRTkfWdmAqpSdKH5dBgjJhDkFqdoDRcEoakuNvpOK8YicORLxoPSXc5YO3QoGIq8UjAlY0drLWKIROVOWBMGjC8H4rlDhQC8YW3Q6gu2FOfqZNxzmNzPPO1gz9h@GGYO9dlx0VwXyYBQBiAI5fX@CuYI9IsYk0OS3UEpJDBlAieR831DqPXVGEihR8SLuEQ4FMoBjcGAVixOsztZKoQTl4h3tWIOq01sVVRCPKi6YYtYqKxgXI7S5G0ae0fq9M5Smgk6DJ1qVXUchL0Dz4rFJIDGqd8g0oD/A0S8Do/Y6E9W4ATGEGSMCqZgO4a@pImVJXWemt8QIRVQ06XGSIYfAt2Oy2Yjm9fhKFLRGJU5ibl8Vjez6v7RvEBy9KlokmXLI3AJMf2xkENxHW8Lcgj1q3snSH0zkENfEOMdMkwzBhD06wwiCSwsmmAUhJt8ImYHPLwR17CJGZqZ6bPGfQUJndNJZkHOI68iz1O9ZXoMeXWeC88STxFAZv6A0Jq/K0ZmJQTlK5MEfpsTVi5CMDRtxXLeeemVpBgxRcGItXrqZt9V7SIZUi1FWjkXqFBDkeR5nPt3viuqYsPnKOsOJpzhcElWTJiLEUO8RAQXnh5DUotYHS3A3LnTeUE@oC8fJaIhvvbUF7EG4u0waJOtrgCzfEqo0nA@/AML2BcQ2cWJAKxAJU33t/zui/oS/iYsM@mFBJsLKZZWDDW@SSGFcsR1yUpUUiWocGM8XZzEzcijyc03jsQlzlzii/Q/5GYE71TJjNeo3Kvlg0Rlx0HCBUgNiQk6HGKlafs2GBulAaEsVFP9tvsqCMTxg1letPyStUlc6XiCHBp@NipjHQZ7wOm6v/KDsn5Qmie4HwynVYHiEfWGkeOK9nivAVjs5D4m/GEeKq3VCryGL/6z1ih1KYKM3Jwt99sZ5En5GVcCVeKOrMAKqA2dUA7SfAVRWkNRkQq5/cMAx6nxA9UAcej07iGxUVfTy9Lwkp2XI/ZGHgblx@nlLuGpju6VqwTGt@CohfVdemkJKwnlMKOV6zQYjOVg5ZVogwoC1lr2dUB9rUC4mxgpIT/vQd12xqKDnpMoC8CCH7YEcr3IsXfXPWCOeDRRNI2CJTRZtw@F3K9qbsAL0AKcjlU8L8jmTFK2YFIBwWe8nxvsGwxwXDD1KfUpLAYXJkzzso2pu4dUTfc5ERqnTo5T3mXmdz2qN8VeGHhTG8lijrhmK3YBLkFISqCi5lx6Zwo7n@HVAkTPUlZ0nLTrUBZ76WNMf8DkVFVLIrrOw6eK2XlKb/yx5VK4DYir8sR3l0QFg@wlB8JSacpxkrBth7KD35tEK@OiWhAXUS4QRshueoM3Etg86cAeL2GxohRMDKsy@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@s9vxES/RSHxLjDVPMcegRbUvcDmucn2ljM8dZdTRKC8yuGiI6ip7d5qnRpiryGElanxVndHR7jDya@iQIvgGoZZnFV5Ahgti02RYfh1FrC2tU4EsQ1aoHjJyo2SubhKL4cVE9tZYfDc8dSQpuSa46BKk4/rgKiqDRQ@cZzplKXsPMnlQkQ@83s6IugmpfHNj1XdlHsElR/5WgpQ8kt1N20@a@FVuJsr9BJ6U5XrrTA5cvQdVt90ZRlllv9zd5/fF2vCPE2l8Dzl9elPC44vQGgkQYjoPNhVQNlhH9TroJaMs6rbwtXxLyyIfisNwVmv@9RTuHFdZsE2mKMOsaI8i4gwHVD6W52UGV7tc1YJDl74bIOUyybsHF6KBq4RMP68LZvmaEw7WL6SvrtxqHocDjJSrOiC@8na59RowccoE/m/SsG3ScvfBOnoLK3JJ6GVfBBeq/NbF@8u57S07weUIvDq0zJhUrndK2NAun6s60QHZZosBXqyvtt@7Q2D5prCeAvVtUFkjHZk3V0jaOBK8XPnsDyMpA5tIWTfk2i2b1GDLpJGYo2/J817RTVWVRHwvwpvwEr6WZRRKAtyMePYiNsY@nUdMPc8zGqrkp736y/808dN/fvbrnwbHEj1v4733849VgSV55lePRE@cr@9H7k9Ps6j38/Z4vW9z6TPDo8t1c4DnNn/fmsdmPXuPYgqYcTD6evHzFDUINdC3r23F7uYgJhGsiVmd4xeN/bz7GThos8yGziu7L3Nu2rPalx2ckzKPUz2I2hyv@rocwTeN4Fa@b0a3I2Z4brj31dV0yWaqlT@@zXr2yH2r/T2Q8aK28jsNl4uW65YieoXA6sz24Pp0tcHlQVCS4vfbN@fiu5/dEfze6XaTm9F9DnatiAk8rYHmeAPdCUM5g83MH2nfNEKnsqwtByfktn3evJ4P3HjSetR4XzvCzUw75@F/VW3idfVb8zK2HeH0NHkaxfESa2rk6NJkciPMkc1fsRL5bQXqjsVvNzYbFINU3W9CD59pUYJXK0mxyPpFeSg2xiG2aTcL3syMNTWPbZ/Sqf6ltFqqfniSusEmNud6He2mbJ3@l8mWCye/9XU3VmMtGylbDLWH1xPbs599hONZKTHZzfZy2Wji@LajVZ9ziZ7bJksivI7VXtVHb5D23OwNsTmqnJYzTvXh/9fiK7P39w9sd0tn@y6Wvykb0m2DTvSVnje1RR@uaPrZbtouudrDWp692q39@vVf)

Went through a few code generators to keep it under the ~65k character limit for answers, [this one](https://marsipulami0815.net/cryptomx/bf.html) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

## 31: [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 890460 bytes

```c
f(i){for(i=!printf("v->{var b=new java.math.BigInteger(\"1");i<890286;i++)printf("%02d",-"xxxxx"[i]);puts("\");for(;!b.equals(b.ZERO);b=b.subtract(b.ONE))System.out.print(0);}");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NC4JAGIT/ii4E71Iu4k02OwQeuiTUreywa6tt5Ee7r0aJv9006DjDzDOTeUWWjWMOmvZ5bUBHbmN0hTmQztv0nTCOjCr1cu6iE6wUeGNbXewqVIUykBJCuV4HXC@X9N9b@MGVrMgHyVlfvDCkvGnRAkmn7DzBXcnUsxUPC5Kd4kNCuYwks61EIzKczGQfU3p8W1Qlq1tkPzL4lA8TYhhLoSuY7sIsvg)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what exactly is supposed to be in place of `xxxxx`?

Comment: @Makonede > With X replaced by the number in hakr14's link.

Comment: But then how is that 890462 bytes? And it doesn't seem to me that it outputs the correct number either.

Comment: @Makonede I encode 2 char into 1.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the exact compression method used? :)

Comment: @Makonede `00`->char 99, `01`->char 100, `99`->char 198

Comment: OK, cool. Also, I've fixed your bytecount, since Unicode characters after `0x7F` are encoded with 2 bytes in UTF-8; in other words, all number pairs that total up to a number \$>28\$ take up 2 bytes instead of 1. Still, congrats on your score of \$257{,}633\$!

Comment: @Makonede You shouldn't save the code in UTF8, that makes an intended 0x80(`29`) into 0xC2 0x80(`9529`)

Comment: Oh, so you choose to encode it with an SBCS. Got it. In that case, congrats on your score of \$890{,}214\$!